# Print the SARS-Cov-2 (COVID-19) genome

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity

### Background

As you probably learned in biology class, DNA and RNA are composed of strands of nucleotides; each nucleotide consists of a chemical called a base together with a sugar and a phosphate group. The information stored in the DNA or RNA is coded as a sequence of bases. DNA uses the bases A, C, G, and T (standing for adenine, cytosine, guanine, and thymine), while RNA uses A, C, G, and U (with uracil replacing thymine).

### Challenge

The genome of SARS-Cov-2, the virus that causes COVID-19, has been fully sequenced. This genome is a sequence of 29,903 bases, each base being one of A, C, G, or U, since it's an RNA virus.

**The challenge is to output that sequence using as few bytes in your program as possible (code golf).** You can write either a full program or a function.

Because the names A, C, G, and U are arbitrary, you can use any 4 characters you want instead:

- You must use exactly 4 characters (they must be pairwise distinct--two or more can't be equal).
- Each one of the 4 characters must be a printable ASCII character in the range from `'!'` to `'~'`, inclusive (ASCII 33 to 126). In particular, this does *not* include the space character or the newline character.
- Each of the 4 characters you use must always represent the same one of A, C, G, and U -- no changing in the middle!

Your output should be the precise text at the following link, with A, C, G, and U replaced by whichever 4 characters you selected, and you may optionally follow the entire sequence with one or more newline characters (but no newlines or other extraneous characters at the beginning or in the middle are allowed):

[Click to see the required output](https://tio.run/##fZ1dki3JbYPXxuADV8AF2E9@9/7D6iI@IM9IEZZGuj23z09VJpMEQZD13//1v//zf3//qd2qmtm/P7e6d7v7@/eq/vvF38/639/ve2r777/798v78e9N379/Lxu95O9H/eLvv/P92X9/3fdj19///l4x34/9/eLvz/m@9C7h@z79eG/7@@ip7zrqe2Hd5Xx/@/ea7wru8/Sx3zvu8r/f9vfN97u@q/3@@b7ue1P9vGruCut7Uelm/17992XzvfG7wb9FWL3@bu572XcldW@/a6nvt9@rvz/3rvX79L8XfxdxF3s/fVeoj25d39T9893GXd53H/e5peu8/fiu5lsmFvJbtu8iblnqrrnve78L0PZ8O/Bd/bdCtwp389/Vf5c1pWv6Xvp98Peu7wa///@uY@6T5276W7HRet8X1d7d3jJ/d/Vd0t4N3ffOLZcX7T5wvsv7TOGzHd9BfxuuVdI/Wvb72Nv/W5e7gr83/H3Od7ffb5vNvJd8X3C28a2JVvt7E8v1vezWdW4NtX/avG/h74pvJ3WTuvjv0r6N0bbu3M93yd@3/33LrUHJlLW83/XcAZEt3gXft3@3WrcOt55n9trQO1r3tbKPu@v7mvvOOz5nm3zujE6UDkLfWo0Mt@6QfP9w2XUXfHf9vV67ctY6GIDM5m7rXqZDUmcJu7xR7/52qfQX61f8/dW3qd8bdQBubb8rOX/BW2/TSkv@fc/iPGZstxjvLQ5H4z74jNsehlN@J2zuYOgb79v5yLOyu3adxtXd61ifjWCl2iIdp89YzmZ08Vp/GXGPb8mGNF4Abd9nuHqxT@W5qtvsPrd3/o6PLXbu7uKOxOc8dJDqzvIZhHatzheckevELDfbWiLZ7x1Dn5o7I581ap21EmerOF955rNVnW19bLNErbfdYbRB1px163Dcnehb5dp0a@fHdIblHOSvzk6w8OXgy0zO5ji3JY@khdHuEDP8Iffi77bu1Nx@jHziyufrcu8m2tulw73jMPb5upU/ketSJNOX1jmI0elbffvtpJwq1ln4WPn34Zo5a3d/rXv8jrgO@5bO@v0/Xp0woLVUPJJP@s6MouBionNu/Czk9mdeWDkfLMdzd/J9L@Hqjl8pjK7NtmX@Z5B1f@pF5wS0pPcR91l9XvYWY84qbuW14950HcQ7R2N3XnzC9sb3Lo635EhLbrV12GPKQxxbrbcc2tzfnE/XKT3j9K75PCnUaYGWLb9DdlebXW6/xlvKd50/1hHkMC2@6L4Bp@aIrW@55Vx5FGxgsJC2A5FZXTzSbtZyGSCdO7AlK@A0jO@rmxUhRt0eKCSArS6od8UpA4BW8UBvLHAb7uU@W0YozLBxIzJjmZacShFxZBV3C7iy@@Feow25kALw2SI@TtyMAINQxwUOufsRpLsICfa4A3UmbJhZBp/1luy2Vc6/OdylU3@3oLB4P3LX7RcVe62T2@UYR9yRXdzPvj75Hz7mXM2dN0xfINancRWMBPfkb4kbQxQ4XysTccSa1QEsh426YCJswY6MPnYO73JOddxb7pAXsIk6RD5ad8RLGyOMtYYizScPPtbhrDhE/uc29kIiUZV90tXI3@mjLu6BnMvBp9gahVQQyvb61Ppb@n2jLIvPHIVCLIIYoX89n3C@RylBcYq1Ns/L4@QvQJVQbuFUhP/22bBdgSBWYS1yu8R3MppWVnJfIPQlsCQ8Im@iSDQvfGhtsF593sjMDqbfR62MXj4jiQEZDLmIXNM/nPbt0C3jGid4Uw7Y6pXnEttuasEMunPd5RfxdVBLCGTxJbOAJrxrG3JtjuKU3SggeDl0nSig7yADkyMCPXU5wuvXd2Hro31L7fMXP43bUe4p8zj/qgvjjAzXztEuJazgEwE3pQTNt1VwBwA1q4rHPch/9rMNFMSpCjwqb9bRqByH@I1K7oiRg4Hl4pq9wHJwygK0k6CgleuNR9V9kB6QICwhXFvZBBYdQyMNGbbMVWCsibr6KpLE8yO1tpkKDFDEsfHogHNQHD7ITUnidDwHdFxKChVeHRuGA6LTW1rMNrKe8wAzdnW49wYzKHeWJWJ6fOrm04FReMNDPGCJ5/PbsbUXNwEcsVeDAhDuOE@rHJngOw3KgBAwA8L2VdJZnRYFlgZ2gOdxKY5eYihGoaE4F@S05ZtSXClnjLfC2lV58OL4J30GbdqA8CUNKBTkly9yTvfj1oYoqJigJexsoqKV1o3VExBzZuR7Xu/jyq@aDuBGEila9wpCbsE/uSklIIB8BRFlNL0ODyu/JtqnyC/jpgh/MZYt7OrW8z7s0JTyDePt5ZAuabO/astkCOfp1oeYMoQYoK7P@BmwcqJVpGpbEnCiyBvlvba4NfCXeahlj8ClOq2cRAKQ4AgIYV5kYn1JNDgOwKoWeaVgCnwaQZH2yopsUcRssvgDSXfZZj6AdD6YpoVI42wMSxQpn3OhqVj2EqFa/NU6FinNvOOnEJHkgp0b3YudGxsNCrGnsnlXOav0IbqYIi8mkmrYOwBYxUOWoTjY8CfaCM2XMZ7uhNwYZN7kW7Nx8NluQx2hgXHGBEqvZc3P38ajE8KInTY@LarYOm0wEK44v/JIOgf69rtG00TrjFJBPSssiEhONA1crPUyDJnF4L0HqreLaxCRATUXY3AEJN8QWVLKCzZAukjCa3CfFX9QYj4XMGwGqom1RNv2SfG@lXF1vSz4ZW9rfFJiRIhc6@DO33A2O@YmE5iCQu8ffl18V3H@eyEYQWncPy5Lvl1hycBv3@VreXMxDW2C2@sfxkOsSjdsapUTK6L3lqMPsFABBb4jdgXidUgBAhWLNv1wo3Ihk70inng9XmHDbzprlV@TZbZhFUzSMYakRc5O4F6@lTwQPQLCa4jb4vocEPWZvUlP1k4qUSBJO0yqcrQVBanTqkKCiBRR/Vq2zsboBgEBQqZOJ0W2DX6VC9sUN9aRQvQxQbP27S9sIedWZBBUmO4QbG/OH5zc5CM1UPdHuejDtacitRaSg@ip8waYfClYhbDX@bRNTs7OGuAprSFShuTW@QTiA3BI7GF2migOs9f6qHEOWCauyQ5MAqi@ALurFYJ1Xy5pbTlaTLwFIU4ekTqVlu9nB9ZVIBc2FvCh/JNN3HqwWRcBXwTPw6bKiMcRiqzP1EXSug3ra9Ymb@x97t0r38lnE33W1L/KJfxNoKl98yqR2IBvXE2bfaUyJTA8XhyVS5av0tXyK0Bmw9JSGCxKIPiMVU6oHVPlyVBQ8Gzb3@38I1VEXGvBZ7bIfj4PrsERkzsXYesvkKclOdEXOBEOMwmacuHNMdE8cgsq4PSJ8vnasm8sBxfoGFIVyh/jFJ46ESve@BvOyvjELD8kZ06NKYGY7A@EpJRmdAM4d/umUaiKD7x4J9ejiEt9FhtT8qWjR0VB//Pxhmdr@ByVh2AJzMXy31ea6TVCVv49BA7ApCiedSkDdgI0Gm6xYNVzfaLBmxT80iVAuW6jK3YFgxR3oiygqYjKtTg7Hq9Gm3ElGEPzGHw2xqribUxIOZogAcYHC@qkhNBJ1tkmM@3xXIMtk1SgVz6cI1DK4FyRW7JL0YPxAILKKZdQ4jGzriJGk5OYtViV1VJLwJUIG3ZKF6lfN3kGhdduMz8APbLZbz1bdCrZ9UibMNSWtp1DjQ1tXfMkN1zykWW/HLJMy2g3RB@Eu@MWFtzLhTfugIgz1QmFdhFlslrx6CH2oSz4vNWYYicNesDMtFDDUq2vzS50cxSaSj@V/FS3AXUCfgstf@BEyVDQnQs9qm57W5sMWnhgkRqErAd5ukD8UIWO1GMayzGrwnd1m/CW84ct71SGZJsSgYxlGPrheERwvdP7epXEpQTHxsEZWnNCCYNK2BrN4iKE@l@G8rh7KEqzpgCz58/XZUSdcbKbETcjbJ/EiRMeaDOwJY81lTNCToDihDAk@CZoCItFRbHb1lCUo/LJDsxWK3Dknc7PIj@J2gTW037GKGLsT/i4oW7fwfb1kmtcP9njWiMBeTu9RmRQ66oz7CuLlMUDLrqRCShTCvw7uN62N8XoAzWKe2V4RQpvwqMMhsiIXNt1CFho8gbPVQfyoS7ZdsF1RdYudARBVJEMOzQc9o4kK1Y9ytgjS0HGKote9EuIcEhJN1VdXePgqZpcp60DKWqX0WpwEMueJLA1KTkkt@gBRf2HVfZ9HzU1kydDzfU5LRgoEacbAc9Vt8uZJmm61AqX/i6JUoXSh@i@lFbui62kGusUD76vH35uYop27PQ7gKk2s4a4SZIupDIuoDk9Z9natWCxDW2/@AN@UbgssinBICCcyLQBMeZOoidxZDJn6/zXVUstmxVyDXaS4MWirtRl0C918jiioU3zfJQyEejBjWxoLE@C9m9z8OVDCER1SLMfGOLdAkTFeokqwT8h@QN@tCUajdbPjryBlvNLVcvkvaTjDbIZXWIHz9aPdAUododsRKMGfB3XM2R0qhYJUe2zZURaJmJdAW1Va5eYOO17KBOtRvXzODQpGxVKFccmVbBU5Nre1OjCq2E5SVJ4kjNRkxiizLvZ8nZRaW3z4pzXPE/SbDOHKo80tVcyIFejdS9tTU5HXicVE@cAFO1c27hK2jUOCWK0GcNfy5Ks8Cn7aWssnmLNaisgL@fXhbF2ZSKVPQQvVFv6VeBdTWtHc7xC42P0/xJqkNmvD2fctPPAoghkUh3gtC7x@F83SXQ/lz/UsU2i4qabX8YWG3kXfPiStBCtdHFmWob8AW6vuYwxbBtAM2d2y6zBpEjspJBMU3dqXDTJAqmc8OEU1RrsMBZ8TO8T4wx1k3qpBvUHBMkAIkpgVOBIxFx/7WhOF@7Wa2YaGUIGBEIJxpgZUCfecMNBlIV0MGpIa13ZMtFaKEPxWLWudVoBiFbH8N1h36nxmE4NbhBtVKZpkCA9FDGWkIxZ7eAsnTrOiv4eeuwKLooZ4HshsUY6sSlFWZ1n34ijIjXTqaoYXhNE4KWUSHLwZCGPs7RoGlitLUHYrFx4wyRrN5PZPr5@H2EASwlSgP@lMOco7FDQqUvKglBQDHoDeZFXCXnCGPy6iyFwbuuKicpDXV5/5LBKKxaxh52AveWUWYayjH1D@ASfW6OSonYoam7R3ruiLJKkXee8ohIh1pvVglvmBOm0Wt/BEgy15o7eZrh35/vlmNvP/ybsDvGv7F6KS8LMoMf7FQUQ6CTvtZ59KQt0yqaAimR@qK3aUh4K2JZ/UOQK3kpN6nkw2xtqPJT8TlWUyb/knaKrxYdooyzu7VC7XTnbZWZgkLIM1cC2WuxVA9AkNCEHLZD4Co6XC2pfqKUka8UU6gSXceXuiQ7N/UdNJ3c383xSp9Rq4CCdHAoOW8VS/ALDjz2hejNcL0Fw36GjJ0iKxNY8Hj8AQtaVk3VrSqGQ4h1rRz1mkvG2g9ZFvQou@wbKojNBFeItQDhBAmbilOJa0tW2Vt/kDsUW0uHBQQhg9P6wssYphhxZK5QtDZODgxN/2CjvOKTEVXM14l8pkOmzDnXp5gmOqPS9yBa3U5Ki58XF47KAp165Fr@wIWScmNAJ4y8XhSphCKUzElSDA2vy1QBzDQ5NhhLKFf9QopYpHsFSqp5kNCdRsVfrftvgacrWVKhR6k30Cya16gk/xzDHNcxuKzcdCE8ARrqlpWwDUtfXzamsS9WuPtWryBuGIAeoiAVSWjJZ@PoGEhbgS6OFI9FMMbxccbfv23QUpWAIUKm0QqSfKm4J9v2JRDCZ@sHvJgT1TZFcbiScsM1lLRgGb76QDLklTwuZR9HXmha09kOm84Ky7c/ZCgJgYt2L1z9NBtZuAo84UhscX/@4wrY@mtu7NR1a4sbZXqci5Dp/UY6ICgzOWqGsY4dh8VnCMeKdeuVVEAYVRnyw9WFJT2aiZUI10oEAzgacUFkwKxvprh8XRXqBSQ95R3Q21Jx@0lDsmRy9kUiJDN/ITiX4IAyn2oAOxZxUNHEDOyqnQL1n0jzBxo0BZj@xq5j4ZGo1EVmTefSTlBqzuDDr4ECyjYUg3KcvBjZC4SWEJQJe/975hJoeXnNJu9rV3jhUk@cQZkz0uRkClSy1F0vi9tUqvQhOhsR3lrqa9BUFBepUyAr6BQr9h3jabtqQc8y0wRarD68sC5lUY5b@rlVI6kRpmjH6OdjulC3USmZRc9rcimKU9VMo1i3dopxBbVmc/bgeLkgC/tt0i8mjLv6BOoBzIFXDFEVCdcPwLYVT0DGuFmtVwaCiTZS3ux4d2b1FMf4YKrXiecrsGfLOcQkrzo08zxRpHCYyLHEJuAVH@PRB4Anb7PdaNAEcJfls@jXMN3RVOpUmDl5kjtKccr6F/oVURoswhohwa6vuDcu6uLeGn7IoUXkrGlQDWJe@0S/AzMGNuKd4oqCvZxsUKH77SmCkKmBHTahRYXbMD62IbxYLef6ZF6pOQFWjsEYobS7UzDJ8ikjZntcgONYFpkQoTCduasGUTZoOiyJL7jIzTQIVRxTpAHpm3NOkKWzIW8GD7ZZJ0I8ZACdzlK9JkR3ZFU4bNpUgTg0NmKp@2Z7Q427vUFmG8O2ErH3uaQQWsm3gvFkKvivX35g9FrQuSOqdji3AdaIH0nNBKVxMOswrTKK8m5WVvzUZe@IyTYQh2xiQylagftM2bLjqRF9IYEweToetqXClkeE1sscWR@GyksvNT1xtmpYSGfp@lIzoTNear/N5aJfKqv8JkONqSBgoHALMyL1Q6JQvoyP9E7q3LhgM8fQshgnrmQPJ1NHQqL4PbbCvlF3RCNlfTnX6/iadbS6oTb8SufszdDeTYrH0FAcH2vahuENdzoHdBGSIHKED@sUGQcSY4S4b4lgP4tYQbaL7cjSAwEd3o//SMSjrppH5J1eDP63o0N2uWo4sP@3IUieG/4hoFlHXZt0sfU5zCNZbiZ/lCp9lKXhuSTTXp6gsCaEzpMtdfTRxTlyovBxQyu2N3A2oHNapTHbKVMfqYyfT6KwqjDvNlPJtSNfdl9b0XTtH7PjAVa8tYNV3ZTVemjSs@jNiJNITaqW6fYMg6HCdjRhq3TlhEiKNmBNjWFfoC0g@SKF6LAtfa246iZvTLxSlFWRFiHNPAf1Bbv5@O4hgTMMVrO@mSIvoW@Tupg842vMS5UPH9Lrl3X1brzdMS0dVRe73ElJ0TSdT0rVabVH7kyutW83sRcb1YXfllmPnA6KhKSPLSvONuzqmX/ndSjHHCS@nZm/Y4sqlRamZvWJ0ytfrSKMq6QqFu7nMMzUeiK73CVmwrxvSqkOSSa8zp36tEnDzNU6Pe/fkFidQlIOdxViOXzlvTL1AVVNGF7RoGzW15W4GVek19miBmnDVDiSWsJVbjoYiRxp6hJtJztQni19NxSOOiHL8M4@cL2oCk3KOa5iNSFVE5sCvGPvRQ@/WwRBg9aO0/m1eocxONUkCgUZmDowJtmgEpWmJb9gqD/cQaiePSCu2xYEuKmpXf2S1KX5WWzAIVoPQrk1Zng5smFraAIp@FjNOAjCqb3tygRu0Orl6CESNK2n3zFm999OjZVkuceR1p7lNMzFU3N2@uDuvKW0nWrxXuDa56eDIaI2xQA6eC@ttxy1n711uknjlSN5ocTABhSZs88uGUg/EukTgJDejgcociVtBkG0wJkQ9LC@vx1pcvCUYSShdZkbaDa/MSHoc2bh5izkyAthki1YfDi07SENULpgOSecu6lSK1zJeN@@6@oPUZdz1R4/pRIFitOhQ0MZhyXA33EeKRZ7FhLW4aMYuW03A3njXYCtp146fdWPJuIhruUJlnM@wPrQ@gFxD89m3jEtfDbuHEtdKgvAkP307KKFc0ucqO7XBdCKmyyqt5z9a/A1NxUlx5VsdLFYOt7tYNgjBwva2eFooCIJVMPnHi7vO4AIDeHBf@o/jkKqr01pXya7WCqnpCFfwoxn4YMUBPb/7RjQ5SIQNjLLK87B@JbcEcd459VuutbLFnalM8nA2Z81hCqzu94pZbvpo0mhrLMQ1oKZDSqgqmZyPefNIQccjQso6EppKooWI1BfZuZwEcMDjdJyvPbYfIi9qzdCN1vO2u4Xcqt6QyiC6Tdv/j3x@3ppgVG44dWW8oeCczL6upshCHH/bTbwD8OvXd5gxQqHFTZqpGja/Zaf9j367341zPyh7lOkNiCusNwhaSVzr9Dpag89YjkehIeSJviKsRbJsK6slrKCEbTGLIilqImZdTI6b00YxWLhtYvEvs/0zsivaKEj5di16IhwDaluxIuOx9IwhcXHL7CJCPzeNWH4Y8RrYQeXFtq7QpOnCbFvN5KyUP9JDSQNWUPy8uXf92hHod2fE1r6ZRU2QUzS1XMVrX5Yge0hHGWuXPYknAK4HL9VvG8c75kXiZ05P8cKdsqZH6BfZh5LKzGUZiRF61T2POL5@hl5YfEpXpedkoMnsDO1480QOUkjOFqlrp6XjV@7nHkcUDeZ0JkggnQ1UWzoNNzR@9Sbq02cB6YS60wNRMkwLuNybsRkCqwwogKWbjJ70yA3n7DQ/MTTxdftTxu83rgH2zzJhK@Xdk08/sk5GGyN1OjgZMkfGZ3V0XBD9XkXXWUqC8/rOI8kmwk8kHQEbk@bk7aTFDFoxgFnDDMVYpP0Zr1dKEeoJPy3O9kSfdjViKhVXZnYyQxLPXElDfwaUEGnHzZkuQHhchBsuilv/USW6R6SsSaSpFh/nDrVOHBjPF9IAvd6MWKS/b@l9eOL5ck8EBCLcs0VlbxgN6aRDUnsow6ZmgIwWFYK5x3aodWHYQxcN0SSHcFvw2iXkCjcT6jxLyo2xxSc1OcT68ztdmco71WfXGfnkdqF@U328Q8ZxO@F81hl@rSHj/GMBdcTeWcvoCGZV/MAtW0CP@5XeHK31cvVva7A1zuNJekJgvrrCAMZDVeia8Hi9yswlc2xFLGEyhhv91rmlvFJHnq7yvbtZPbgM9E4Vz4PL6qcvNQXuXg8WeL1t6IG7nzZPWc64@x/quS32c6UkQ05cFHVL1pv1Qu82iKM7DTQRJWYYxdB5D@/DORha5dH6bGbjeJ4hmLeeFJaeoEz2Lb8K9tb9RIC5SIL6p1MmlbkRmT2ZfGiRqifplFUKiO2sIqaDjFoLegnlXa8ht50MlJXHKdN53BAsNpJfN@q8LlqinU/GZvZLhgXIaboEMk/NXm5SS/u3cZ4nqiW9b5R2luhT5M1krfpBRRk@Wem4GWdpSnTmtWasxbeeKTNhVmFFqf@jBhz3BP3gclNgmyEN6eOBUrBSVlNGXlfdmt56k0ALotuS2gzW658eCe@zx5hk/IudGB@cFkzDp4wT@xkLUxZ4xaGT8eLEPHOoLfsnt5TKJjlVZRoVmS0OpCu0z2Q6i8dg0vkQyyerdtsF@Cx9pGw6vqHTRhTliuU/CBG7@9GvHipliamNfMfjQOsxfduR49AzIGLRZVf5uqFTmEFCRMdUu02GtpvsyuOd2hVgRuShrpXyR03Ew9hqOaExKLf0GXAaarrzFYw5Lbc9MomLEQceVdupXmTagmc1J4XoTJB5Qo15svOQji5peCbwOz7UACsS/LHysl2lTLO9x1lExYWUfjMvbhJeLbUfFxpRyXgUrQUs1ALrdStbF7KZRIFxxe28ltX26LIZZ1Ob2SYWJiUHQ@I77lR6E8LdNDIeJUwiFDICxr8fZeBzV9Ji0JRGnO1IlfCTtIdSg6nMh0RvPOQwcP30nrhjKpYZ5tGC1UpzjQc@LGUlU/OQCJA8Q0cb5jIMnqn0I2dIjwUoriPaZjkMuD6ZYrssaoW9x@14slFlQHS6Czw2zqSqZY9NcuC7rnRwZwgHLOUi8dwHiQGYHoXKgFM6e1wzgVOjA8@iwJ9KP4M0EEhN5h2L3zI51bGNf3R/TJoBM6bTc67WwNcaYZRrljPw6IFIgt@MereQIIWwitlT@qlARyjztETIvBEPWaxuQLmUHNdTiMkMzQD9yLU3k/EsL9w0yrnAmBkSVhYBcTsa0/SsUaUw899htrY8wd7DXczy0LUpZoBKTWbTGEUrRK8R2WSu7LhgQt3LjVTtgQ1OnjJkeKj@IMdDXf7oMuR1qpOBw70BpBNub4nGw9ROvPGrYOFIp99JRDnHtdejipp@Mg@Ij8gcAVWED56i5hqyp2Yhv@6BSVerviUg4QAzCxthC@PNNnJcO5G10b3hkWZXGDMXmSDPYVBsX1ffeHBEuzWypYX1rAZkewLg7QkAUTi3e0R8KN1Aq4HuzGGHAKTMnI4bt0xLqNaphvt5BB488uQk7zSkY61fo2NnWMV4MvZ0O0fk6R3RnHtua6eLuvYNfHM/TFWmEE5MwAT0@AYtO3JhGneelj335@7T9ssEqGOkrQtEY9WtjyndhM4eLNssj5rbQC1K9@bWPAYjneEe7U9bURorx1MoPYYuauhXnvfEgdAnqcbgqgxGfhpF9zU@1NNRyPDfrM0816E9EZhxR1d0n3mTTtqioHnh0sVEPZAjQ7mmPYN1nMi76qcunXpFZPely8Yr/cwZmuM/emw0a5uXbhCRUOSLyvA1joi@Y1fc0aSFTXvPJZAQ1oK5qjzXYJnfg6hzIth19x0P@HCDgB9UM7@PyHnTxKyQ28jvrXLzKBWPFFdS4w4rtdxshlf4iRrpmfPG4EChON70in4uzGnbkzN5HO/knZwOJtS4NrnU60xEMu6kfqp9VpNtOtVfjxvMqhqeUou9UkkbyXkHMgBhEb3gM5hw0eszQrOQHrzT8xqDHTulcsijC3T7KJ8bZZnHFlNCVqfMeGuRbOnpPnWGOi7TNUbo0WJWC4qH9iOIikEZTFJCrNAZdgmDwzw8FdOFFF99rVCfjh/JgMSsrQHsSlfT06AyF2OMaDt0RpTQFKfHT8cpHwv8pzt@nVFYJbqerkHvPBeQsXymLTIE0Or@fo/gcE/IPMqEsvM/hthWvadBMACK8du2rLIEG@Hx7/RNSnBuKbTDrigJPAajPfwvT/1hOs44oUefNaG3fzSWmWAIKLW8MCXuc30imzzTAkdrUYcnZm1aOkNOupHWvcwu/EhnjhSdZ1Upg7fMD3phNr2q1XlUVPp8qzztO3XTpCX7gEfTvGhuwqX7@cdjHDIRdeoJvdcyZ89a2Iq3wPt5uAReKxnxm@IbViaDoSFXaIDMtGs/i6P/bc9/6hZIm8v6ukxVYARDGfxmBEsGBfV7sk37CQwOsBpvZuebO@3N9AsSrXXLyGQyXXn60HrIXzP@x/NZ@BwLrj0psdHah2Rkw/s9cGD35XljCsu99zORi8OzC6BuBFflbdJTLZhNk6bUDY1c@1sv@kkV0Wue9@ufaXxOk/V8HAdcinc02qdhjIjTlg/JUdKQewW6dEi0H2PQkSMw4hBYsC4Jydv3pll9GZjnZ3hZ7STJHsPUQKEZAuXni5kodsPdWIjs8E2E4elX5hh5JlpVxnEtn@bOCUR/68ICjxJ5Y7t4IswbHe9WNEva3EYEFTZ@3gR1ys7zD6wGlqixnkaq3YGmrt1JAzHqrqk3nK/9YABNFkcjMgSH4ekeznaWYOI2IdGMSGrinFLvg9lgMPeYj/bwE0/TNbR4@vgOfBw/rsQ9kCT3Ay2clppMcwIpOQvwVAJHJLh5Nx/61hG0MIaRHjY/o4HJXKYs6/FF7ceXrTXT9KZ2HnGkxpIQ0vuekYJ5pJyDNN4cUT8A2Brgp6yDacc90TyMLQGxnjO/nskIc3S0Zuw7k5rdX1pwmCkL0uP3pPtTHoCj@OA1AbR1p241qSyYevXDbdpq@LZR8QDCcTCyNDqPD3OZPGzBZLQ@bV3vITMQZd0hOfysKBegHV3N6ntsvh8ThKLhyXvaYlQmAOYhHKILIF7HEmQgaLsN1rK/Sv95hhG3X1IZUGyiDoHKGIwNDwlsP/4Aj4j8fZQH6nkSjMFmwFLaxniKZnqgyeWYROYJ9y/RCc/abTmjBxlNJzJPhkj@///5Fw). (Including all 29,903 characters here would cause this to exceed a StackExchange maximum size.)

Because you can use any 4 distinct characters you want, it's acceptable to use, for example, lower-case instead of upper-case, or to use T instead of U, or to use 0123 instead of ACGU, or even to output the complementary strand (with A and U switched, and C and G switched).

### Restrictions

Standard loopholes are prohibited as usual. In particular, it's not allowed to retrieve information online or from any source other than your program.

*I've removed the blanket prohibition against the use of any built-in which yields genomic data or protein data. These would generally retrieve data from the Internet and that usage wouldn't be allowed anyway (as a standard loophole), but if some language has this facility built in internally, without requiring Internet access, that might still be interesting to note (even if it doesn't solve the spirit of the challenge, which is to find patterns in the genomic data).*

### Verifying Your Program

I've set up a way to check that your program's output is correct. Just copy and paste your program's output into the argument in [this verification program on TIO](https://tio.run/##jZ1trx3XcaW/81ecOHBIWi@RnAEGiCwDhRq5ECDIAEIq88HRB5q8pC5MXWouSceesfPTRzm917NqN0XKGInkPfecPt27965dL6tWVT/95MXTpz/88Le3d09fvn12c/nV6zfPXt7@7tNvf/3gnfduX/34rfvbuxfHew/@9tnN89u7m8vXX/3mq6@/@pf86vKz6I6Iqr7@7Mjszszj94i8fnB9rb/Xz7Oi8/p/Xz9cL69fOn4/Disdcn2pD67/1/Ezr2/neplx/Xs9oo6XeXxw/VnHRdcQjuvp5fra9dQVxzjiODDWcI53r8ccI1jn02mPb6zhH5/mceX1Wa7RHn@Oyx1fitNRtUYYx0Ghm70efb1YHV88bvA6Ca3j180dhx0jifX1NZY4Pj2OPn72Gutx9uvBxyDWYNerY4Q6dWp8FevPcRtreMd9rPOGxrnW4xjNMU1M5DFtxyDWtMQac67rHgPQ8hwrcIz@mKE1C@vmj9Efw6rQmI5DjxMf3zpu8Pj3GEetM9e66WPGSvO9LhS97nZN83FXx5B63dC6bq3p8qStE9YxvEMUDtnxHeSx4Jol/dG0r9Ou9V/zskZw/cL1PMfdHp8mi7kOOS6wZOOYE8328SWm6zhszWutOdT6afGOiV8jXiupm9Tgj6EdC6Nl7Vqv15CPq1@vsuYgJMqa3mM8a4NIFteA19WPW401D2s@l9hrQdfWWpeVfKy7XpdZ11zbZ8km563SjtJGyDVXJcGNtUmOPww71oDXXR/Ha1WWtBYCILFZt7UO0yaJJQndfFHfPlYp9Eb7iOtbx6IeX9QGWHN7jGTpC766Fi005cd1GuVRZblFeNfksDXWiZdwW8Owy9cOq7UxdMV1dU65pGyNXbuxdffa1ktGkFItkbbTISxLZjR4zb@EOMu3ZEEqT4CW7xBcHexduVTVWuxcam/pO04brNy6i7UlDuWhjRRrLy@B0KrF0gVLyLVjmptNTZHkd21D75q1Rw5p1DxrJpasonylmZesam/rtMkUpb62NqMFMmpJtzbHuhNdVapNt7b0mPawlIP01ZITJLzZ@BKTJXPs25BG0sRodbAZPsk6@LittWvWepR0Ykvna7jrJtLLpc3dZTN26LqWPpHqkiXTRWMpiNLua119raSUKtIZ6Fjp92LM7LV1f6l7PLa4NnuH9vr6F62OGdBcyh5JJx17RlawEdFaanxJyFqf2mZl6WApnnUnx3UxV2v7hcxoW2xT4r8EMtZPHbSUgKZ0nWKdK5eWXZNRSyrWzGvFvejaiGsfldV5cIbOHt3bKN6QIg2p1dRmH1Eu7FhrvqXQar2zdLp26RJOr5r3k0ydJqhZ8rXJ1mhnldPHeEm51tLH2oJspkYXrSug1GyxdZU1nS2NggwUEpJWIBKrZY@0mtEMA09nbdiQFLAbyveVyYxgo9YayCTgWy2jnjFKGQeoZQ/0xcBvQ72sc0sI5TP0qBGJsURLSiWwOJKKdQuosvViHaMFWSYFx6cD@1ijZuQwyOtYhkPqvuTSLQuJ77E21BJhu5lh5zP2lK1llfJPNndo169bkFlcL7nr9EHBWmvnZtjGYXckF@u1xyf9w2mWqln7DdGXE@vd2DJGcvekb7EbhRVYulYiYotVrQ0YNhuxjIl8C1akdNpa/i77VNs9pQ45gEXUJvLWWls8tDDysdquSHLmQsfanAWbyH/Wwi6TiFVlnTQa6Tudatk9POew8QmWRiYVD6WzvWt9ldxXlGRxzpIpRCKwEfp16YSlexQSBLtYc7O1PEp@GaiQlxsoFfl/vWXYqkAuViAtUrvYdyKaVFSyLiDvS86S/BFpE1mi2uZDc4P06nwlMVtu@jpVS@ilMyYwIIIhFpFqekdprxVa09j2E7woy7HVkUslptVU4zPoznWXh8XXRg15II0uqcZpQrumXa6erVhhNYoT3Gy6HCugaxCBSRHhPWXYwuvjNbD21l5T7f03ehq1o9hT4rH0qwbGHinGztYOBaz4J3LcFBIkV4vxO3BQZ1bRuMvlX/LTiSuIUpXzqLhZWyNmO4zeiIkdEXJ8YKm4ZC2QHJSyHNoao6CZyx6NqvsgPCBAaEy4ljIxLNqG9jQk2BJXOWOJ1dWlCBKXHom2zMS4AbI4Fh5tcDaKzQexKUGctmfhHYeCQplX24Zig2j3hiYz7VnX0gBVVnWo98RnUOwsSUT0OGvP2XGj0IbL48GX2Do/bVuzURO4I9ZqQADyO5amVYyM8a3EywAQMALC8sWEs9otMiyJ24E/j0qx9RJCUTINwb4gpg3flOxKOGJcM6xVlQYPtv@Ez3ibFiB0SeIUyuWXLnJMd1JrhRWUTdAU5iyirJXmjdmTI@bIyPfcXseWXjUcwI2MpUjdKx5yyv2TmlIAgpMvI6KIJtvmoaXXBPsE8eWoKczfCEsHcrXmc51seVOKN@xvN5u0CZt9qQ6DIeynNT/YlMLE4Op6jy8BVkzUslRpScKdCOJGaa8Obg3/yzhUs0b4pdqt7EQMkNwRPITalon5JdBgO@BWpcArGVPcp5Irkp5ZgS2ymEkUv5ykNWwjH7h03piGhQjjLAyNFQnvc3lTI9mNhUrhV21bpDBzbT@ZiAkuWLnSvVi5sdB4IdZUFu8IR5XeRMumSIsJpCrWDgcsRkOGXXF8w5O1kTcf9vF0J8TGeOZJvFU9Cn6W266OvIFyxISXHs2cL307Gh0Thu208GlShdZpgXHhgv0rjaR9oKuvMRomakeUMuozw3IRiYkqcRejPQ1FZFFo7wLqzWAMAjKA5kYYbAGJNwSWhOKCHkc6CMKjUJ8x@iCEfDbOsBGoxNZibdM7xesW9qtjR8E7emv7JyFEBMvVNu68w97METeJQAUQep7wdeFdwf7PBmDES@P@UVnS7TJLdvx6D1/TO4NJYBPUXp4QD6EqmaCpEQ6ssN4dtj64hTIo4B0jV3i8Nim4QMGkVW6/UbGQwV4BTxyPVujBNx21Sq9JMtNuFUjSQgwJixydgL0cM7mc6JIj3HZxU1ifDaLOmT3hSVtJjRWYoB0kVTFaC4LUblUiQUCKoH5NW87C6AZxAuSZOpwU2FboVQbWk9xoWwrBxxjN6L2@oIXsW4FBQGG6Q3x7Y/74yUk8EgV0vyAXnVxrKlCrATmwntpvOJM7BIsB7LU/LZM1e6ft4CmswVIOyK39iYuPg0NgD7KTWHGQvdSpyjFgGLgmOjAIoPwC6K5mCNS9GVJbcjSZaAtMnDQieSpN32kF2lkgJzYa50PxJ4vYsd1mDQK8CJyHRZUQly0UUZ@hiwnrelBfozbzxeyt3j3zOfHsWJ829K90Ce@Ma2rd3AokepxvVE0afSUzJWe4PDlKlzSX0mj5CCczQWlJDAYpEHRGKybUiinzZFdQ7lmnr@34Y7KIqNYAz0yB/ZwPrMEWkzsXYOsLSNMSnOgCDoQHmcSbcuLNNtE4cspVQOlj5eeyYd0YNi7AMYQqpD/KITx5ImY80TfslfKOaV5MzDw5pjHERH94SAppSjeAcrduKpmq0YHL3kn1yOKSn0XGFHxp65FR0F9vb3C2BM9RegiUwFgs/@/UTLY9ZMXfheHAmRTE005lgE7gjQ62GKDqMz7B4EkIvsIlnHLdRsbIFQjSqBNFAUlGVKrF0XF5NtKIK8YYmMfOZyKsSt6OCClGk0uA8IGCOijBdBJ1psFMazznYMMgFd4rJ2cLhCI4Z@Sa6FLw4GgAucqTLiHFY2RdSYwkJjFq0UqrTS4BVSLfMCd1MfnrJM4g8Zpp5AdHj2j2mM8UnEp0XeImFLmlTsdQZUFr5zyJDZt4pFkvmyzDMloNwQeD3XELjd/LwBN1gMWpyDGFVhFhsFr2aHvsRVpwa6syxE4YtB0zw0IJStUem1Voz1ZIMv1k8ie7jVMnx6@B5ZdzomBovDsnepTd9rImEbT8gYZqMGA9nqcTxNur0JbaSGPYZsXgXZkGvKX8QctzMkOSTZFAyjQMvVg4In69w/vYmcQmBcfCgRmac0IKg0xY25tFRcjr3xHKxu6BKI2a4phtfd5OI2qPE92UsBn59hM4scPHtSnQko2aShlBJ4BxghmS@ybXEBSLjGKmpSFIR82ZbZjNVmDLO5yvhn4ybBNQT@sZexFlfcLpirx9jm8fO7hG9RM9tjkSgLeVbY8MaF15ht5pkTB5wEk3IgFFSuP@LXc9LW@y0cupkd0Lu1eE8AY8ws4QEZFzuzYBDUye@HOR4/LBLul0wrUF1jZwBEZUlgw5tDvsFZmoWPko@x4zFUSskuiGvwQJh5C0J6urMRaaKol10jyQIHc5XA02YliTjNs6ITkgt@ABWf3tq/S@Hjk1gydFznUrLRAoAac9BJ6V3Q5HmoTpYius8LcJlGIgfYDuFdJKfbGUZGMd4oH35fafE5uiFVv8HZypNLIGuUmULqgyTqA5PGfa0rlgoQ1pvXhyfmG4NLQpuUG4cALTCo9x7mT4JLZMxmwd/zprqWkzQy7xnUR4Malr8jLwl3LiOKyhRXPpKEUiwIM9tKEyPQnYP43BhzchLqpNmvVAYe8aR1Sol6AS9BOUP9yPNEUj4fpZkSeuZZ2haom8p7S8QBajFdiBs@UGXXEUMwdshKOG@1rOZ0jolC2SR9VbliFpGYh1BjSVrW1sYqXvIQy02quvjaGJ2ShTKjtWkwWbjFxam9q78GyYTjIhPMGZoEkEUeKdLHk6qdSWeWHObZxnwmwjh0qPJLlXIiBno3UvaU5ODr1OLCb2AV60Y237VeKusUkgo1XZ/TUtyQyfsJ42x2Iz1sy2wuVl/zoxls5MTGYPwgvZltwZeGfT0tYcrZDoGP0rogaRfXtzjpp2HBgkgQyq4zi1Uzz@tSeIzq3yizy2QVTUdPLhyGJC7wIPb4IWrJUGZ6SliB/A9pJhlN22wmlmz3YYNahJEjsoJNLUndovqokCyZxwcpJqie9QJnxU9ibjFHmT2KEG@QcIyThEpMDIwBGIOf@awzltsFvPmWFkABk8EFIw9plx6oQb9mAQYSIdiBrUWme2DLQGzFA0VrRznWYAwtWx@26z79C4DKeO3yDYKAzTQEHaXkSZQlJGtcfP0q5jr@h94LGVcJHNwL@XJ5ZQJ3pSUWbnWTeiqAjNtKtiBC8xIuBSCiTZeJKQjVmaNI1brSWB2KxYuAdJ1mpOZLvx@t6AASglngL4L4k5W2Gbgpy8pCQIBkXBN5AW2ZmQTYxBrzsZAubWzpgoPZTh@YcOq7CiIXtYCVhbVhhlCNPYewCf8c/NUZmk9kDU3KK1dwyzSJR27fMYlgi23qgW2DI7SLvV/A6moMg15/Btint3vB@2ubn175jdwv6F1UswJMQMeDx3UgCCzsS95rM3aYGctClOxUR@sK3SVB4S2KZ/kOQaf2tyUluDWd5g48Hkd6iiSH4H7yRdTT6EG2Vybw60mzF7O4wMFFSWIhuYZovtbACchMTkwAUSXsH2ckLtMLWkZM2Ygp3gNK7UPdYhuf9h00ndVW2dlJNqteMgnhwMDktFk/zChy9rQtVmOF8C4T4Hjq7xpAhsjePxAieknTlpl6YEDCm@0VbUZSQZbVtwXVSr4LTvuLLwTGCFeAkgThCAGTgluTbhapqrb3CHZAvhcKEg5GBkn1BZ@yl2OWauYLYkSA4KTvhhwrxjk2JXjdUIfyVBpnMtr0s3j3GEpe9JNrmdlBQ1L04ehwk8sdO16IUeQMaBCZUwvrggVBFDSJ0RoNo5MCdfBTCrwCGJUAZyRT@EoGWSR6CUyifZmxOp2LO1Pk38adLWZKhh6tXwFwxqxSZ@lt0c5zAzzdy0IVwEMMItTWXaIXV@3ZhKO1Xt7FPsjLzdEOgAMWSBSS0ZLNx1A2MWwEuHC0egOcnwcMbduq@nomgShjgqMaUQU081agn0fZNEEJk4@e8GBHWloVz2UDhBm8NcMATeeCERcoqeNmAeSV9zWuDaF5HONsqWP0crEICxddten4oMzN3EPWJL9fjx8c4I0/xobm/NaVESV472cjJCzvMH6YhhgYFZy5TlyOGg@Exh2eOt2OlVPAwyjOhg88MmPKkaLhOskRwXwNGAAyoTZiUjmXFSUYQXiHQRdwzPhpzTKQxFnonRE4qUwPAe2qkIH5jhyTbAQzEmNZy4Ah2VUiDfU1M8wcKVHczcZFch8ROpRQ3JmsgjN6XUPosTszYOBNtICMR96mJAI2ReBrCEwOvPHU@o6GEXl6SzXemFgzW5FEKVgT4XQ8CSJfdiSlzvXKUnwcGQ8M5QVZMuEUCgDoXMoG9coffI01bTdjnLSBtoserwwrSQmmxMU9/VMkk5VppijNwKNnPSFiolM6l5ytyCZJT5UzDWTd0inUFuWZh9OR8ulwT/r6daTBq10Q/kARwDKRsmKzJQNwhfkzjFO0bVIq1KGMRwE6XtVo2O5N6kGJ@GTK1wnjB6Br2znMIa5UacZ4h0FCY0LGEJqAVb@KmDQBOm0e82aQJ3lOAzqdcw3pARU6lUo@AF5ijMCcdb8F8IZTQJZRcRbK1VvWFaF/eW4FMmJSpuhYNqB9apb/gLIHNgI64prmHQx5YNEhTnuhIQqRhnR0Wow8LMET@4Ir5ZJGTrZw5UnoCsRiCNQNoM1MgyeIpA2axdIFjmBU6KUD6dsKnGp0zCdFAUSXKGkWkCqFFEQx2Az4x6qikKK@JW/MF0ySTejxEAB3OkrwmRbdllThM0FSNODg03VfWyWQOPu7xDaRnMtwOy9L6nEFiebeLOG6XgWjP@ROyRoHZCUt@0bcFdx3pAPZcrhYqZCvMYJFHazczKc07GmjgMEyHIFgaosjGuflI2bHfVgb48gTJ4WDloTQxWOjS8hPaYwiicVnK6eZOrDdOSIoPfD5MRnmmb87V0HtylMOu/xpFjNAQMJA5xzIi9YOiEh5FD/ZN3b14wPsTms9hNaPccmEgdDo3y@8AGvVPZMRwh68uKnLq/mso2J9Qqd4rc9Rm6m5pksfgUyx1Iy4fsDnk5G3YDkAPkyDugXqwgRJQR7rAglvkgLg3RIrouRw0IvHV7@F/aBmHeNDT/idXAT2N46C5XDVuWUzmy2ImDfwxpFlJXz7yZ@jzFIUhvjP0MZ/hMS0Fzi6LZ3kVhSgiVIRmu6qOIs0aFSsvhSrm8kbvBKwd1CoOdEtUy@9jBNDyrGMSdYkrpNqjrrktL6q4dI@bowFatLc6q78psvCnSMOvPHiOWHlMr1u1uBEGFa/WQodqVEwYhphCzRhjaGfrAJS@oUFmmhbc5NzmBm8MvGKUxnhUmzjUF1Ae5@HuvIIQxNVcwv5skLaRvgbs9dcDDPQ9BPlRMt0veXbe1a8M0dWRVpH5XQAqvadGUNFazLaJPsVK71MxapJwfdlVu2HZuR3RgyqFlTfGNqzoqd/rdTDHbCU@nem9Y4sKpRbGZPWNUyseuSCMr6QyFq7mMMyUaiKr3GrCgdzWkWYcEk55ndn2bJeDia5Qe9@7OLQ6gSAc7ijEdP2a/0fUCVk3Yu6BE215Tmu5mp2pqjd1aIGqwahsSU9jCJUdFkmMKeuQ3E5ypTha9OhmPUUSk47d4zP4iJ1CTznEOMyGpCsgs8BX7ftTQu3RwALA4Ma3PxSuk2ckmiSCQ0MxxY8a3SAilUxKfoFVu7iGvnThiSrFNDnRSUat6otVO8jPShEF8NQDt6EnLU4ENUksZQFDPYsRJDozy2@5c4AKtnFh9AES1K0nXzJm9d6rRMi0XO7Kr01ymOTZU2F1vu1u7KK1ruHg7cW1w08aR1hplghw4F9KbtluO3jNcJLHTkXzR5GAMCkXYxpftSm0n1ikCB7nTGiiMkbgUBNoGbUJUw7LjeqTFyVuMkYjSYWQkXfBKj6SNkZWLt@gjIwebaNHsw6JkB2qI0gWVA9K5inoyxW0ar4t3nf2B6lKu@qPGtIaBYm/RpiDth02E24N9TLLIvZiQFifNWGWzCVgbrxpoJeXao2ddWFJO4pquENPOp5gfSh/wXAfms24pp74SdA8mrpkEg5Oc6nZgQjmlzyhzcoNTiThVVlN6fuLi98BU7BRnvlXBYuZwuoqlx0MwsT1NnpYXBMAqN/mkxZ1ncIIBf7B3@I/iEKsrp7QuJrpqM6Qqh7iCHp2GD2YcUPPbu0WTjcSggcOscj@sM@UWI843K87pWjNbXJlKJw9Hc@YcToLV9V4jlj11NFNoa1@IMcCmg0qoLJmUj3HzoYKWW4SEeSQUlQwXYqi@0M6lJHAH3E7H8dpG@wHyhq05cKP5vOlqIZeqJ6AyHl1P2f@JPl97ThAqF5w6M55AcA5md1XT0EJsf9NFvIXjl7vucNoIDSxu0EzZsDqnnfq9ervzwrkelDWa7g2QK8w3GG9l7FpOraM5@LTl2BAaRJ7hVwxqMVG2mdUiVpDCNplFlhQ2Eb0uarabw0YhWKhtbPEZ2T617BpuFKB8OhddQxzD1TZjRcJj6hlN4kYts4oQ/Vw0YvrhkNfwHZReTPMKDZo2yLbZTI5K@TE1lBRgjRdfu@9d7nIE6t1psdW7Z1Fi5GRNTVfx3IcpyG7SEfa1w5rEHQDbjZfiXMaxt3kQ@BnTk71wpazhEepFentJYeQy7IlhelU9Dzk@Tk0vTD6lqtJ9MuBk5jTt2P1ElkshOttQXXNKOs50P9c4wmgwplPjCUxlA9mWnIIbCr@yx@pTZwHoBLvTDVGmmRbucva0zZCzSoMCULqa1pNuueGYneInmibuan/S@LnbNYD@mSZsprxr8qlH1s5I@0g5FZw0mSPiMzt6VBD1XkHV2aQEa9edDyUbC19D6Rhno6Y4uXPCYhqt2IFpuxmysVD7p71eKESITfw0OdsdfdLZiIrJuNKzkx6SaOaYMPTUoARLWy7OdALC7SJccBHc@omV6BqRMCeRolp0nCvUcuxAub@QGuhlT4tF6vua2odNng/XRAAggj2bVLab0RBO2iSlmzL05Ayg0cJCMPaYNrVODLvpol000SFcFtxWCTPCng517iXlwtjgTEkM0T5/TlWm4k7V2eW0fHK5UO6uPl4h@3Fdg/m0I/xou4z1zgRqi@29Nq0j6FVxcrcsAVmuV9p9tNrTlefSYHOcy5305IF5dIEAlJuqUDXh9noxPZeMsQW2hM4YLvRrx5bSSjn0dKXvXc3qxmV472Tx3LgsTnWpk@DOdmOBXdsGHzhzc/MU5ZSr/4Ge02Q/Z0qmyYmToi7J2r1eqN3G48icApohJU4ziqLyHtyHfVCUysP16emN436G@LyxqbDUBE1n3/BRoLeuJ8KZG0pQniplJjNXArNrOh@apOpOOmGWAmQ7s4ipICPXAl9CcdcuyE0HA2Hm8aTp3G4IFBvKrwt1dhUt1s47o6f3yzQLkNJ0CqQ2mz1cpDbl3/bz3FFtwvuEaWeKPkne6awVJ69omk/GVNyUozQFOrVLM9rkW/eUqUFWQUXJ/8MGLNcEnfxyQ2A9TRqmjgdIwUxZdRnZVXVteGt3Ag2AblNqp7FenmokvM5uYzLtX6zEOPGUYNp9mnZip7YwYYLXKHQiXpSYew6laf/ElmLZTEwV042KyBYFkjGwT013FrfBpPJhJJ@o2mUX@GdTR8qioxtyyoiGuWL6D0TEzNzwq5tKmWJqIe9yO9DYSF/n0HGoGRCw6LSrdF1RKUwjIazjZLsNhqaL7MLtndIZYFrkwa4V80dFxEXbaimhslNu6jPO6UDTOZegzWm47JFOXLQ4cKvanOzFdFtwr@YJIXI6yGyiRm3a@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@4TLodcqT4Yd7AQgnXN4yHA9DO6ONdwYLRVq5dyLMOcYeGypK6sncIH5I5hCohvjgLmrOIbtrFvTrLJB0leqbAjIY4PTChthCe7MeOq6VSFvodvNIoyu0mRuaIM9hkG1vZ994cES6NDLFhXWvBmh7csDTHQCG4ZyuEfGmdAGtGrrThx0AkDTzVNy4ZFpEtZxsuJ9H4MYjm06yd8NUrOUudMxpVlHujF2ZjhF5esdwzt23NaeKOno3fHM9TMR0IawRAQPQ5Rs07ciJadT5lOy5Prc3t18iQB5jyrrwaMy69TalmtDRg2mb4VZzPa4WqXtja26DMZXhbu1PWdEUVpa7ULoN3bChd3reHQcGPplsDKrKzsipULR34UNsHoUEf/fanOc6pDsC0@5oJd2rdqeTNCmotrl0MlEP5JimXJXuwVoO5J31U5VO7CSy69Il4zH1zNM0xz@yLDRtmRdvEJLQ0BcV4asdEXXHzrjDSRs0bT@XQERYE@Yi5rkGTf8eSJ01hF1X3/GADxcI@EE1dX5Ezu4mZoZcD/3eLDe3UnFLcQU1rrBSyU1P8wo/UWNq5rwwKFAgjt29IrcKc9i26Uxux1vzTXYHHWqcm2zydQYiaXcSp2yf2WQ9leq7xg1kVQVPk4tdqZK0J@cVmAYIDekFnUGHi2zvEYqF9OCdrF0YbNsplsM8ukC3D/M5YZa5bTEpZFXKlJcWypae7hNLUMtpukQI3VrMbEHh0H4EUdAog05KkBVyml2C4NAPT8l0eYo7vxawT8uPZIBiluYAZkxV0@ag0hej7NHmwBnDhCY5XX46TnhboD9d8euIwizRdncNaucZwLTlM2wxTQDN7s/9CA7XhNSGTEg7v9PENmI/DYIGULTftmSFKdgQj8/dN0nBuaTQCjuGSeA2GOnmf/PUH7rjlAN6@Fk18PaJYzkdDHFKTS@cFPdSfQKb3NMCRWtShztm9ZR0DjjpQlrXMjvxI545VHSeVaUI3jQ/4IXqqVWNnEdFTZ1vhLt9T950wpLejkdSvGhswqn7eucxDtMRtWITvds0Z/da6BhtgfZzcwm01kTEu4vvoDLTGBpwhQLI6XbtZ3Hkj9b8lLeA2hzm101XBVowhJ3facEyjYJyP9km/QQGG1i1N7PynTvNnu4XBFrtkpGaznTh7kPtJn9J@x/3Z@E8Jly7U2LCtR@QkQXP/cCB7h3nlSEs195XDV0cnF0Oag/hKrxMeqoFvWmmKLUHRo4@54tOoSJ8zaX98tSNz2Gyno9jg0vyjkL7KRjD4qTpQ1KUFOSuBN1USKQfY5BDR6DFIW5BOyUkbZ89xepNwzw/w8tsJ1H2aKaGFzpNoPx8MQPFLrgrE5FtvrEwPP3KGCPPRIuYdlzN2Vw5AemvnVjgUSK7bRdPhNmt412KZkqby4iAwsrPmyBPmfP8A7OBRWqMzZFKV6CparemgBh2V8Vuzpd@MIA6i8MRKYxD8XQPRzuNMXGZkGBGKDWjnCbfB7JBY@4yHu3mJ@6ma9di8@Nz3Mfy40pcA0lwX8DCU1Iz3ZzwlBwFuCuBLRLYvIsPfesQWmjDSA2bn9FAZy5DlrHxovTjy9qcaWpTcx5xpMKSAaR7PyMF8Zh0DtR4Y0S5HcBUAz9FHXQ7zhrOQ1kSIOs58suqaWEOj9aIfU6nZteXBhjmpAWp8dvU/Qo3wJF98JzgtGVO3qoms2Do1Q@3SbPh00LFAwjLxsjU6Hl8mNPkgxbUtNanrGs/ZAagLHNADj8rygloW1ej@m6b78cEwWjY9J40GZUOgPMQDsEFAK9lCjIuaLoM1rS/mPrzaUacPiSmQbGBOggqZWeseEhg@vEHaETo76U4UM@ToA02DZambIynaE4NNLEcncjc4X4HOoOzZprO6EZGlWOZa5pI/vX/fvbgwdNvn9xfXr569fu33//rk9@9vPnt57/87998cfn7v7/Ey5eXm5c3393cvXl9ub27fXP75OXt/7l5dnnz6vLZp/ri/c0fbu5f3/zz6fsP@@FHn3/zxYPbuzeXm/v7V/eXLy@fffHg@t8fXt0@uzz99ubp73/z6v7frid7ltdzPFonevr4weXyf69/L7fPL48ePb386svLw8vDx5c///ly/e3Xl4f/@fDxccyFw67/fX9/vcbzRz/76uuv/@fX/3g5Tvbk6Zub@8vDnz97eHn19s3l1fPrQa@@v751/@Tuxc2n/373s4@vl/qCE3h4n/PGX64//nLc@nuDfLBu57snt3ePjhdP7l88vZ7oGPgvfnH95Q@PH1wHpd9v776/XvnLi@7rF48fHZ//9vNvjquut8Iv0i/KL/r64jj//c3zm/ubu6c3/3xz9@LNt7y7zvzuO/z87vb1mye/v7k7hpqv3t69Yc7XZP7y8jdfrhGv6dPk/WjqvvrjdeJe/uny6u7mOPLtseaX29fXcfzvt7f3N8@OiWPWbv54@@bR5/rlL9cr/Gio1wu/fnP/8ubu0Tw19/Ea5Ax9H7HefHwM8z@@vX15c3l0Purv/u7y6OG/3z28fPmlvv3b06efXKfzdDfnTz75Yr91/so3mhJGfczL@WrXGfrRjfz0ZL30bfz82ceX19@@evvy2eV3N9ffJF6n03783klPc/jLPYdx8T1eZ@bpt/d77j6@PIzrJvhkP4P4urMu@deOz/ePr792fL1/fP@14/u94x/MDPXr27sXS5TXRnx9@flT/X95ft1oh@q@ztGapfj4kh9f6uNLLwF4XyuE9suP384Pv10fflsnXxolDkHKx3/@s17VvOrjVc57Oe@VXv20IPzrtzcfvNcn9zeXu1dvLt8/ub3/j9vXN5dn1@15e/f0zafv3/r7asji@flx@fXRGsGSmX9Y93PW1o/e3r2@fXF38@xxHBJ@lZYvfuqAXAfkTx9Q64D66QN6HdAPv1j7/n3NHw@PAw799qFPc32aP/FprU/rJz7t9WkfFz4k6dHt2s2X28uv3tGKl9uPPpKRwEYcEzmi@tvbb46N/uF7e4TG@ObxN5iZbWgu7yvYjz46xnL5gCG6PDk09bObP141wj9eTdHTh5dDK3x8mQucvnmM72/@/wd0utZVOx8ydmjsq5V7cxXF56/e3r8rjx/P3@uc/fzpT4jfEsGXr28@cJGt3Y770Pc/sDynQZ8n@/E3@wp/ebAX5H1r9eur8H/2gWn3OD7/bFbgfIeffHK5f3t3ub7@7vbuyZt37NTo2f92HsT697DwVylin703mr3d1lc9Ne@qgH/76ut/@s0/ffU/fmwZP7NWX1c5HIYHP/zww1d3h1vyp2OBrv7Ii/sn3z18fTgoh6fw7dVAHC7VdVZvn//pcvvm0//39PnLJy9e//DJ/3ry8uX13@ufpQf@Cw) and run it.

### Other Info

Some facts that may or may not be of help:

1. There are 29,903 bases in the sequence. The counts for the individual bases are:

   - A 8954
   - C 5492
   - G 5863
   - U 9594
2. If you simply code each of the 4 bases in 2 bits, that would get you down to 7476 bytes (plus program overhead), so any competitive answer is likely to be shorter than that.
3. The source for the data can be found at [this web page at NIH](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/MN908947); scroll down to ORIGIN. The data is written there in lower-case letters, and 't' is used instead of 'u', apparently because DNA sequencing techniques were used.
4. There are variant strains of SARS-Cov-2 known (the base sequences are slightly different, and the length varies a bit); I believe the one here is the first one sequenced, from Wuhan.
5. Groups of 3 consecutive bases code for particular amino acids, so it might be useful to analyze the data in groups of 3. But there are non-coding areas where the number of bytes isn't necessarily a multiple of 3, so you may not want to just divide the data into groups of 3 starting at the beginning. If it might be useful, you can find more info on the structure of the virus RNA [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7161481/) (but this probably isn't needed).

***Disclaimer:*** I'm not a biologist. If anyone has any corrections or improvements on the underlying biology (or anything else, of course), please let me know!

Happy golfing!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Output NC\_045512, the first sequenced genome of SARS-CoV-2 (COVID-19)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/205873/output-nc-045512-the-first-sequenced-genome-of-sars-cov-2-covid-19)

Comment: @ppery The post you refer to is a duplicate of this post (which was posted a couple of days ago in the Sandbox, which is the recommended way of proceeding).  The other post also is missing a verification program, it has no prohibition against genome built-ins, and it just isn't as well thought-out in general.

Comment: [Discussion about the issue of question priority on Meta](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/19018/46076)

Comment: I have to ask the perrenial question: [What does banning built-ins do for this challenge?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13775/56656)

Comment: @AdHocGarfHunter I originally didn't have any ban like that at all, since I don't think it's usually a good idea, but when I posted it in the Sandbox, mypronounismonicareinstate suggested it, saying: "Mathematica has `ResourceData["Genetic Sequences for the SARS-CoV-2 Coronavirus"]`. It fetches data from the internet, but somebody like me could argue that it's allowed because it's sort of built-in, so I think you should disallow coronavirus genome built-ins here."   So I went ahead and added the restriction, although, as far as I know, it doesn't really limit things at all.... (continued)

Comment: (continuation)  ... (Are there any languages that have genome data built in, without retrieving such data from the Internet? That's prohibited as a standard loophole anyway.) And, in any case, the point of the challenge is to see if there are hidden patterns in the genome, which I think is an interesting question.  @AdHocGarfHunter

Comment: [Genome Organization of the SARS-CoV](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5172239/) may be more helpful for info on the structure of the RNA.

Comment: @fireflame241 Thanks — this has a lot more information than the link on the virus structure I included towards the end of the challenge.

Comment: Just as another reference, [paq8l](http://mattmahoney.net/dc/paq.html) is compressing it to 7260 bytes. Another version of PAQ may compress it better -- I've just tried that one.

Comment: More interestingly, by separating each codon with a space, the size drops to 7143 bytes. This suggests that PAQ does find some kind of logic in the genetic code.

Comment: It also seems like a manual dumb arithmetic coding-based approach gets 7318 bytes (ignoring overhead that will be significant), and the computed entropy of the string (should work as a lower bound for non-magical direct arithmetic coding, huffman coding and other such stuff) seems to be about 7315.35 bytes. I suspect that my entropy calculation is wrong, as 9594 Us vs 5492 Cs must skew things significantly, but a random online tool agrees with it.

Comment: I got 7316 with arithmetic coding. https://ideone.com/lFLw6s

Comment: @Sopel Do you encode an end of string marker? Currently I do, although it would probably be shorter to encode the length instead.

Comment: that's where the difference comes from probably

Comment: @AdHocGarfHunter On re-thinking this, I've removed the prohibition against built-ins that yield genome or protein data.  (The standard loophole provision prohibiting the retrieval of data online remains.) If some language has this facility built in internally, it would be of interest to know that. With that said, I'm still most interested in actual compression techniques based on patterns in the data.

Comment: @mypronounismonicareinstate Your entropy figure of just over 7315 bytes matches what I got when I calculated it. The entropy does go down, however, if you group characters together into, say, trigraphs, and regard those as the basic unit. With trigraphs, I'm getting an entropy of just over 7183 bytes. (There's going to be increased overhead though in any actual implementation, so there's a trade-off involved.)

Comment: @MitchellSpector How do you group into trigraphs? I tried to abuse FLIF even more by grouping the ASCII values into RGB colors (they just happen to be triplets), and I get 7796 bytes for the image (I also turned off the normal-image-speciific transformations where they were harmful).

Comment: @mypronounismonicareinstate For the entropy calculation, I did something like `fold -3 < genome.txt | sort | uniq -c` to get a count of each trigraph (plus one leftover small group at the end), and then I added up `-count * log(count)/log(2)` to get the entropy in bits.  Divide by 8 to get the entropy in bytes.  (But when I applied flif to an "image" file obtained by replacing each character triple in genome.txt by a unique character, the result was a longer file than the flif file you got from the original data.)

Comment: `zpaq nsivc` got 7360 bytes.  `zopfli --deflate` is 8072 bytes, `zopfli --zlib` is 8078 bytes, `zopfli --gzip` is 8090 bytes. Not entered as an answer because I haven't constructed golfed decompression lines (because clearly none of these will win). However it's very interesting that zpaq produced 7360, exactly one more byte than the [flif-tools answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/205923/13951).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Sledgehammer, dev branch, 136 + 1 + 7196 = 7333 bytes

The dev branch is both more buggy and less buggy than the normal branch. At least `#` and variables work properly in it.

No built-in compression (except that this entire language is one big piece of source code compression)!

Mathematica somehow knows when you're performing one-huge-exact-number arithmetic coding, and segfaults on every single action. It feels like this solution somehow works both only in theory and only in practice.

In the end, I managed to use the interactive app to display the braille code, but I was not able to copy it from there. I had to introduce code modifications so that the "CGCC submission" section doesn't start evaluating the code repeatedly, making it impossible to copy. Here is it:

```
⡱⢿⢧⡷⢣⢗⠊⠴⢼⢹⠐⢀⠐⢻⣀⠏⡟⡘⣈⠿⣫⡚⢂⡟⡆⠴⡢⢞⡞⡝⡰⡃⡟⣐⡗⡏⠬⡃⡇⣊⠰⡳⡺⡺⢨⠐⡻⢈⣝⡎⠤⢷⢃⠆⢹⣊⣎⡎⠬⠺⡇⣂⢔⠇⢅⣸⢃⡺⠲⡥⡧⡇⣊⢪⡇⣢⢸⠇⡕⣼⠇⣍⢤⠝⡁⡐⡷⣛⡫⢿⣏⠞⢆⡟⡷⣫⣶⢮⠛⠝⣖⠻⢠⢫⠻⣬⠷⢲⢊⣪⢮⠷⢲⢹⣱⡙⢶⠓⢖⣥⣐⢜⢼⡕⠃⡴⣜⠽⡽⠸⣣⢲⣎⠚⡻⣕
```

Since this code is nearly impossible to execute in the normal Sledgehammer environment, here's the Mathematica code (made unreadable by copying):

```
comp = FromDigits[Import["f","Byte"],256]*2^-57567;
freqs=(Divide[Accumulate@#,Total@#]&)/@{{0,2881,2023,1742,2308},{0,2084,888,439,2081},{0,1612,1168,1093,1990},{0,2377,1413,2589,3215}};
l=0; r=prev=1;
Print@@Map[(
 f2=Rescale[freqs[[prev]], {0,1}, {l,r}];
 {l,r}=f2[[{0,1}+(prev=LengthWhile[f2,#<comp&])]];
 prev
)&, Range@29903]
```

Outputs `ACGU` as `1234` (Mathematica is 1-indexed).

It performs a weird kind of arithmetic coding that I came up with myself (although it is obvious that I'm not the first one): the probabilities for the next character are estimated from the previous character.

Requires a binary file named `f` in the current directory. `xxd` dump of its contents:

```
00000000: 25b0 5b51 d075 9b20 aa7d 28d6 577a 4c3b  %.[Q.u. .}(.WzL;
00000010: 5cdb 5777 bbb9 5d5e 436e b49e 329a ec02  \.Ww..]^Cn..2...
00000020: 0a03 b3ac 60c4 344a 70fa d31b 1504 7535  ....`.4Jp.....u5
00000030: db04 0b23 f505 1955 d924 f278 5372 cec1  ...#...U.$.xSr..
00000040: 2d87 7779 73a5 4921 4e84 6e6d 0bbc c9cc  -.wys.I!N.nm....
00000050: 2328 3fba f150 2d70 1c79 d98a 3051 ee1c  #(?..P-p.y..0Q..
00000060: 86ae 9c68 4ef7 81c9 fe21 6511 23ef 853e  ...hN....!e.#..>
00000070: a2e8 038a 31fd ec9e 4d27 93cd 9739 b8ae  ....1...M'...9..
00000080: 5c72 a357 d397 e360 7199 95f0 d921 5fa8  \r.W...`q....!_.
00000090: b466 bbfe 626b 49a7 fd63 d05b 25bc 09b2  .f..bkI..c.[%...
000000a0: 825f b4f3 3d3b ef96 fc8f 16e0 3889 4ed4  ._..=;......8.N.
000000b0: b6b7 9183 bc62 51ef f5d3 661b a2dc 0e86  .....bQ...f.....
000000c0: 47b3 665e fc12 87b2 b36c a390 d11f 54d5  G.f^.....l....T.
000000d0: 8576 b900 6626 6d3c 0f54 be56 3391 ed08  .v..f&m<.T.V3...
000000e0: 5f3a e64b 647c 3fdf dfc2 bd4e ed4b 8930  _:.Kd|?....N.K.0
000000f0: 1af6 e650 7257 ca36 f433 851c bf57 ab9d  ...PrW.6.3...W..
00000100: 7f37 7ffa bc82 9df3 66a9 2f46 e221 4665  .7......f./F.!Fe
00000110: c1fd 4ba3 648f df4f 46e3 86c4 2175 0140  ..K.d..OF...!u.@
00000120: 3916 68ca a886 6fd3 5812 3715 f45b b053  9.h...o.X.7..[.S
00000130: ffd5 8dad 1ded 6cad 6c35 2005 b94a 81bc  ......l.l5 ..J..
00000140: f713 251e 556f 9e82 a39d 6f23 40dd 00c7  ..%.Uo....o#@...
00000150: f5ea dac4 0d0c 8a4b f359 d195 bb91 8316  .......K.Y......
00000160: 5cc0 c627 c3d0 59e9 8078 9d46 3f5d 1e8c  \..'..Y..x.F?]..
00000170: a756 e4cb 6dd4 ab1a 1d68 908f c8dd 750a  .V..m....h....u.
00000180: c426 2d58 c8ed 2fb4 8942 b43a 7dbb c732  .&-X../..B.:}..2
00000190: 6c46 08ba 859b 7842 17d6 ff47 1cfd 5796  lF....xB...G..W.
000001a0: 6bd8 bc36 c2a7 4d13 a106 7ad8 1016 d1d3  k..6..M...z.....
000001b0: b164 8642 be94 0dbe 7092 ffbc 2a16 fad0  .d.B....p...*...
000001c0: 5f31 5e34 2356 d61d 33ff 605a 8658 9de2  _1^4#V..3.`Z.X..
000001d0: d479 7d1b c6fc 2706 b411 20b2 c114 1ff2  .y}...'... .....
000001e0: d093 90d4 da4b 99ee be05 2c66 ed7f 4758  .....K....,f..GX
000001f0: 8e46 b1e6 c103 d010 bcaf 9209 127d 5494  .F...........}T.
00000200: f0fa 7831 f9ca ca42 d89e 4b4c 15e2 4d55  ..x1...B..KL..MU
00000210: 52c1 d637 dbd1 b8c6 7ac6 c75b be1d 98b7  R..7....z..[....
00000220: 3f24 5fe2 4493 c39f ec67 1cb4 4f1b afaf  ?$_.D....g..O...
00000230: e226 0ddf e08b 741d d98a c173 770c f1f4  .&....t....sw...
00000240: 2cef c968 37a7 33f9 4956 3707 ca16 0c24  ,..h7.3.IV7....$
00000250: 930f d5d1 ff77 53ef 260a 8416 4add 6e92  .....wS.&...J.n.
00000260: 42a2 da86 bb02 4de4 400a 6faf 8625 0975  B.....M.@.o..%.u
00000270: 9cd9 8092 1dd4 4615 4807 ed71 b7ce ef52  ......F.H..q...R
00000280: ac49 4d1d 4b33 0843 8c10 5180 cafb 0d40  .IM.K3.C..Q....@
00000290: cd30 1876 ea2b 492e acd1 da8a a986 2bf3  .0.v.+I.......+.
000002a0: 8d79 74e7 bf0f c41a 414a 2449 9e2a 7b1a  .yt.....AJ$I.*{.
000002b0: 47b1 28e8 f512 bd93 c5f9 9af3 ef2d e8ab  G.(..........-..
000002c0: 8ea3 6995 1511 095f 6fb6 a9c4 b1da a1e4  ..i...._o.......
000002d0: 9144 0e26 b0b9 4bb9 cfc8 b5fa f288 8da1  .D.&..K.........
000002e0: 645e a552 5565 2ead a3c7 b70c a69b 5f75  d^.RUe........_u
000002f0: f048 8c15 6b98 5845 9f51 d1d7 1860 99b3  .H..k.XE.Q...`..
00000300: 16c3 f860 b516 ebac d1e2 a132 8eac 3cf0  ...`.......2..<.
00000310: 68fb 6177 40dd 340c e5ba 0414 516d 9687  h.aw@.4.....Qm..
00000320: 52d1 d49c a14b beca b962 07fb 32b9 473f  R....K...b..2.G?
00000330: 729c 07fe e03d d634 b047 c736 a86a 415a  r....=.4.G.6.jAZ
00000340: c64b 27a5 5bc3 50de 9db4 3f2f 2fbe 24c2  .K'.[.P...?//.$.
00000350: cab1 fc5e 5f8b 976a 855e 90a4 9ba8 227e  ...^_..j.^...."~
00000360: aa03 1d8a 6a66 6e4d b4a4 6ebc d12b 7a1e  ....jfnM..n..+z.
00000370: 47af 3f26 4cb9 a0be 5e4d 5de2 1490 253b  G.?&L...^M]...%;
00000380: b1cf 4be0 cba6 9d42 4c9d a03a 2a58 eb8d  ..K....BL..:*X..
00000390: 8872 a085 0ba2 ff20 27ac ad81 6fa3 4430  .r..... '...o.D0
000003a0: ccd9 da65 dde4 a664 c311 e839 e205 cc13  ...e...d...9....
000003b0: e86b d0a8 4f32 3b45 2fce 9143 ad91 138b  .k..O2;E/..C....
000003c0: 578a 1b4b 2415 f118 1c9f 5619 cd4d 7b13  W..K$.....V..M{.
000003d0: 48f0 a2ba 80ef 0ef1 7ffb aedd 7dfe 0835  H...........}..5
000003e0: ec0d c995 d5fe 1f8e 29e3 696c 947b 371b  ........).il.{7.
000003f0: e7f4 2d83 8845 7fe8 3466 30de 429e 819b  ..-..E..4f0.B...
00000400: f8b4 3567 de4b d840 76ca 1792 6279 26df  ..5g.K.@v...by&.
00000410: c5be 759c f045 c5e2 add5 2baf f93f 7934  ..u..E....+..?y4
00000420: ff48 0d3b 6f03 923f 4158 5e57 d519 45d1  .H.;o..?AX^W..E.
00000430: deb7 1211 1964 a8e7 c1a0 89fc 16b8 c685  .....d..........
00000440: 36bb bcd8 3005 51a5 e77c 5b72 aa1f 581f  6...0.Q..|[r..X.
00000450: 998b dbb1 e75f 3412 bc4a dcdb 2725 661e  ....._4..J..'%f.
00000460: b756 6cc2 15f5 64d6 34fe f74b f971 2ab7  .Vl...d.4..K.q*.
00000470: 75ec ab54 069f 7693 fbdb 2d23 7b6f ca60  u..T..v...-#{o.`
00000480: e0e9 b702 830d 3aca aaf7 9cb7 4946 50ef  ......:.....IFP.
00000490: 52cd 078e 9647 19c0 d472 4102 e309 f53c  R....G...rA....<
000004a0: 576a d76f 15ac dc8c 8a02 85c7 a59e 140d  Wj.o............
000004b0: 4e14 cc13 416e a0d5 0bd5 0d4d a515 1cb3  N...An.....M....
000004c0: bf4b 929b b540 b7ce 3761 5de8 f19c 9fba  .K...@..7a].....
000004d0: acde 715d da96 57d8 3a28 8ef2 c725 43fa  ..q]..W.:(...%C.
000004e0: 419e 2e5b c2b8 2e33 97f7 db4c 26c5 951b  A..[...3...L&...
000004f0: 19d9 16bd f6ac 17e5 470f c650 812f b3ec  ........G..P./..
00000500: c847 cf15 5c76 9922 ceb3 9f79 5a70 5ba4  .G..\v."...yZp[.
00000510: 4168 1e81 304d 8e19 2e2c a7ea 0355 000a  Ah..0M...,...U..
00000520: 5b2b 156c 6680 e1dd 7e09 d351 23a0 f2c3  [+.lf...~..Q#...
00000530: 0442 8cf1 fbf4 3805 a46a 29cc 0bb0 df8b  .B....8..j).....
00000540: ca86 b8eb 4d44 57f9 39c9 8712 2ac7 0304  ....MDW.9...*...
00000550: fa0b b7d7 d2ef 239c 55b8 a4c0 4c5c 4e5d  ......#.U...L\N]
00000560: 826d 0a7e 8a51 cd35 9edf b08a 665a 2dea  .m.~.Q.5....fZ-.
00000570: 243f db27 455b f64e 6def ac8f d562 4fbd  $?.'E[.Nm....bO.
00000580: 09ce 937a 251d 7d6f 7c43 7df1 f9f0 dc30  ...z%.}o|C}....0
00000590: 325f 0d66 db15 c53a 2b91 d0eb 4b26 8c17  2_.f...:+...K&..
000005a0: cd06 f899 a1c5 7478 03fa 3741 ea8b 2385  ......tx..7A..#.
000005b0: 1637 ae62 935e fa39 776f eadc fc83 de65  .7.b.^.9wo.....e
000005c0: 643c da17 07f6 1100 64e5 98d9 a9f5 fe32  d<......d......2
000005d0: ad4f 2049 7339 2aa1 ef38 4a90 bd34 82fc  .O Is9*..8J..4..
000005e0: fdcf 9291 051f b20a 2769 b6de 5f28 511e  ........'i.._(Q.
000005f0: 5939 240a 68e4 8415 963e 96a4 d435 2c3f  Y9$.h....>...5,?
00000600: 6a85 ed07 6924 0344 1989 5f2d 136a 0c48  j...i$.D.._-.j.H
00000610: 7670 a797 9600 84fc 4cc4 9628 f54a e11a  vp......L..(.J..
00000620: 91e3 e13d 78ec 0af5 d97c 570b 7e7c 3639  ...=x....|W.~|69
00000630: 62fc 9caa 4648 9b65 8c96 be2d aa65 0bef  b...FH.e...-.e..
00000640: 08c5 b03e c240 31bf 0155 b6e5 4b48 afbc  ...>.@1..U..KH..
00000650: 2608 0489 f9b7 b235 a722 bf7b 0002 a4ff  &......5.".{....
00000660: 139c 3579 df0f 505e 9437 1986 6ee0 2cd8  ..5y..P^.7..n.,.
00000670: b578 5692 c33c 9531 14fa 3da1 5f73 176b  .xV..<.1..=._s.k
00000680: 9b52 b21a 7f34 cc18 0f2a 8b64 9529 21c6  .R...4...*.d.)!.
00000690: 6ca0 6c50 25b1 bd4f 393a 766c 1edc 17ed  l.lP%..O9:vl....
000006a0: 2d4a a752 5911 d7d2 c4bf 5d71 bb96 ee2f  -J.RY.....]q.../
000006b0: 8fdf 77b9 b28b 1289 f5b8 457a 571f cb73  ..w.......EzW..s
000006c0: 91fc c07f 6337 797d e165 c2ba ba12 9b85  ....c7y}.e......
000006d0: ddb8 2021 7861 7456 af65 b9a4 ec3b 8637  .. !xatV.e...;.7
000006e0: 9d99 7158 8039 2493 6e23 cd5c 83d7 80c2  ..qX.9$.n#.\....
000006f0: 090f 35e6 9890 4871 0828 92d0 046c 9a16  ..5...Hq.(...l..
00000700: a6d6 9968 477f da4b 3680 c91f 1c4a 9369  ...hG..K6....J.i
00000710: bbd8 2339 a0e0 2145 1ae9 e96a c33b cd9a  ..#9..!E...j.;..
00000720: d9d9 c7e8 203b f052 a59d 149b 4ccd 2116  .... ;.R....L.!.
00000730: 562d 7638 f4f8 9b96 c47d fde7 381c 8e0f  V-v8.....}..8...
00000740: 79c6 4492 25fb 0b4e a57a 6afd f825 ab8a  y.D.%..N.zj..%..
00000750: 8f28 ca3e 9a79 cd0d 5021 56fe 3c9c b6ad  .(.>.y..P!V.<...
00000760: 3d01 e106 ac76 950d 03de e3a3 bab0 29bd  =....v........).
00000770: f76b d2cd 1e8c 06db 2f91 f86c f745 bc2c  .k....../..l.E.,
00000780: 1721 168f a873 419c 2e06 55a8 d16b 1e21  .!...sA...U..k.!
00000790: dd40 8708 8bf8 38b8 1324 8455 c469 2156  .@....8..$.U.i!V
000007a0: d838 bf85 4031 dc8c e321 fbb9 c464 d1d4  .8..@1...!...d..
000007b0: 5327 adeb 3df6 dcd7 a427 ee72 2714 fd46  S'..=....'.r'..F
000007c0: 4de6 16af 5335 6616 2997 1494 b693 9cd1  M...S5f.).......
000007d0: c5c1 873b 0138 15b3 c532 7b0b dd07 9345  ...;.8...2{....E
000007e0: dc65 5911 c142 57fc b494 d3f3 915a f777  .eY..BW......Z.w
000007f0: 9925 6803 4eab dc7e 7257 dde9 c70e 7a23  .%h.N..~rW....z#
00000800: 73b2 635e 1c7a 02b1 63af c9bd 69e4 5c13  s.c^.z..c...i.\.
00000810: c0dc 2828 9209 8308 6a49 8700 91cd ed83  ..((....jI......
00000820: 5e92 7d9f e315 1384 a6a7 2ba0 e8f2 5bf9  ^.}.......+...[.
00000830: a40c b7e8 2155 6334 1c3c 33c4 9022 8218  ....!Uc4.<3.."..
00000840: c51f 6d6f c48d d2a0 51d1 74bb 92b9 693b  ..mo....Q.t...i;
00000850: 6c5e 1c45 deb7 719d afb1 c26f 891e a714  l^.E..q....o....
00000860: 6482 f724 0cf8 33fa b96b 678a 1f59 af08  d..$..3..kg..Y..
00000870: 2d93 ae69 a502 ed1a b556 61f5 9b17 43f3  -..i.....Va...C.
00000880: 4aed 74cc 535f bbf2 4b49 d43b 8439 3ef8  J.t.S_..KI.;.9>.
00000890: b03a 669a 333a cc5b bd81 df68 63c2 6a69  .:f.3:.[...hc.ji
000008a0: d07e 4f4c 9f4f 711d f122 3aec f642 d098  .~OL.Oq..":..B..
000008b0: 1658 d4d9 a91d 8b3e 959c d1b5 6368 cebc  .X.....>....ch..
000008c0: 9529 b2b2 4679 9087 2414 1370 571c 49b5  .)..Fy..$..pW.I.
000008d0: d0b6 c156 2bbb 3147 330e 0779 4228 cbe7  ...V+.1G3..yB(..
000008e0: 5ac4 1405 e80f 5a2f a359 9566 769e e73c  Z.....Z/.Y.fv..<
000008f0: 6162 a97c eb96 2f4b 8051 20d2 6628 5e90  ab.|../K.Q .f(^.
00000900: 6df2 4158 3339 8fa7 3d9b d944 e8fa 5625  m.AX39..=..D..V%
00000910: 032d 5b7d ee91 6918 ea30 b743 861b d91a  .-[}..i..0.C....
00000920: e8aa 6a6c 21d0 78d7 a3ba 8348 c9ba dbab  ..jl!.x....H....
00000930: 8ba9 1cc3 28eb 5b34 e21b 4061 2867 e1c4  ....(.[4..@a(g..
00000940: f268 a6fa c99b b290 e0c8 15d3 f201 8dd8  .h..............
00000950: 68db b7e1 cb09 838c 2683 ba13 c550 b615  h.......&....P..
00000960: 7f9c 121b fa98 d7ca 634a 10e0 cf73 d17a  ........cJ...s.z
00000970: 3ac3 dcbc b0fc f001 d4ec eed0 bf84 42f0  :.............B.
00000980: cc31 b7c4 354b 246b 48d8 6453 89db 91f6  .1..5K$kH.dS....
00000990: 94e5 6a2b f8c6 df2b 1c8a 013c 49ca 884f  ..j+...+...<I..O
000009a0: bcf9 162b 8388 3f6c 4413 d975 037a 3703  ...+..?lD..u.z7.
000009b0: b768 b0d7 891a b0b2 2412 3ec8 3771 e045  .h......$.>.7q.E
000009c0: 3c94 d950 56da 7e4b 5e76 fbff 8d02 e8e3  <..PV.~K^v......
000009d0: 291b cef6 fbc1 fda3 cc4f d55a 4663 ec92  )........O.ZFc..
000009e0: 6aff 5666 df39 35f7 d7ea a459 a9a9 a0bc  j.Vf.95....Y....
000009f0: 7f3a 3134 53dc 0091 e8ae 0950 f88a 8250  .:14S......P...P
00000a00: 1fe6 f8ff efc1 59d8 7795 cffe 1506 dac4  ......Y.w.......
00000a10: 9349 12c7 9385 97b9 24e8 1eda bfc1 a2cf  .I......$.......
00000a20: 8a9c 737d 51e9 189e 16ba 30b6 e0d7 d874  ..s}Q.....0....t
00000a30: 8d3d aa00 8966 35a6 4da0 6178 c4cc 26b6  .=...f5.M.ax..&.
00000a40: 2a74 8d6d 9fbc 28b8 16ee 9bdf 97fc 880e  *t.m..(.........
00000a50: ee32 574c aa94 0700 15e0 7506 cc22 070f  .2WL......u.."..
00000a60: e4d7 2551 d742 b8a3 4141 56ed 2e89 7200  ..%Q.B..AAV...r.
00000a70: e8d6 4780 9b67 2e50 1e71 52f9 1f2b d44f  ..G..g.P.qR..+.O
00000a80: 83c1 88f6 0744 dad0 e3c7 2555 f523 0ef2  .....D....%U.#..
00000a90: d7e9 e57a 278a 5822 8cfc 2708 8a36 5113  ...z'.X"..'..6Q.
00000aa0: 2808 5383 1e5a ac3c 3d3f 1dfb d2e9 27b1  (.S..Z.<=?....'.
00000ab0: ef7e 059a fb5d 047c 7000 8448 8a81 949d  .~...].|p..H....
00000ac0: d10c 80cc f8aa 82f6 eb85 ecfc c0cb ad82  ................
00000ad0: 057a 84b8 4dcf 6114 9b98 f37f afa8 c078  .z..M.a........x
00000ae0: 871b 7519 0180 d579 b53c 7a20 2881 46cf  ..u....y.<z (.F.
00000af0: ab85 ee2c a87b f1f3 21eb 8137 0522 6131  ...,.{..!..7."a1
00000b00: 2518 06d8 e6b0 3b35 dc86 4608 6a97 c82f  %.....;5..F.j../
00000b10: 6e35 3c36 2707 4321 d94d 2571 6e88 92d1  n5<6'.C!.M%qn...
00000b20: 8d47 c790 574b f1bd 28a3 ac46 55cb 9365  .G..WK..(..FU..e
00000b30: d230 0701 39e8 382e 16a6 bccb 58f6 3a33  .0..9.8.....X.:3
00000b40: be7a b8a6 111c 8e41 8241 b583 e586 7a47  .z.....A.A....zG
00000b50: d6a8 08f8 1da4 e897 796b 6207 71fa 83fb  ........ykb.q...
00000b60: 89a2 264f 2c43 1323 2a0f 51cf 1e0d 4d91  ..&O,C.#*.Q...M.
00000b70: f3bd 904a 6605 28f6 85df 2c80 8973 16d3  ...Jf.(...,..s..
00000b80: 1aac e49f 5b92 52f1 aced b76a e2a0 0c6a  ....[.R....j...j
00000b90: 4659 cdfa 06f1 2f25 58d9 8fa6 b0e6 9923  FY..../%X......#
00000ba0: 8398 47ac 52bb d825 7801 0196 f9a8 f770  ..G.R..%x......p
00000bb0: 6a8d a924 b5b4 3d0d 16ff 4995 bfd4 d090  j..$..=...I.....
00000bc0: ea4c fa5a baf1 8dd8 04d5 f455 2701 ef65  .L.Z.......U'..e
00000bd0: 08df a6f8 ea6f c49d 2b43 c14d 0d88 1de2  .....o..+C.M....
00000be0: 46ed 3b5f be65 b910 0c17 82e0 6929 c54c  F.;_.e......i).L
00000bf0: 7471 b556 9e47 53bb 8d15 3130 5c49 01ed  tq.V.GS...10\I..
00000c00: 21bf 10a7 1bf9 9ca8 b788 5fa1 3c39 1062  !........._.<9.b
00000c10: 9a74 9fe1 6ee7 ec0e df56 1888 e3e3 0d8d  .t..n....V......
00000c20: 12e3 05f8 a812 a0eb 073a c433 5a62 9dfa  .........:.3Zb..
00000c30: e65e 4754 3bd0 9826 3056 bbf4 c8f6 c246  .^GT;..&0V.....F
00000c40: 52bf 941e 77cb 2513 de85 55dc 38ff a01f  R...w.%...U.8...
00000c50: 9c1e abe9 8934 5617 a9cd 80ad 0622 fb1b  .....4V......"..
00000c60: a993 5db8 5ec0 0be0 7aaa 197c 258f a462  ..].^...z..|%..b
00000c70: 98ee f3af b6cc 58e2 7264 92dd 901f fe78  ......X.rd.....x
00000c80: cf18 ad69 83cd b563 18f8 fce7 2bb9 024e  ...i...c....+..N
00000c90: 2ebf 0301 1b51 3f0d d8f1 c553 5ca4 6120  .....Q?....S\.a 
00000ca0: 34ed 5a46 4239 ced4 d3c4 e19a d128 aa04  4.ZFB9.......(..
00000cb0: 4ef2 e714 3ea3 dd46 f2d4 2233 3db8 9044  N...>..F.."3=..D
00000cc0: 311c 6c20 d0dc 3b5a ad4b 17e9 48a2 e416  1.l ..;Z.K..H...
00000cd0: b73b 53c3 97a9 52fa 6cd5 f9bc f0ea 2bfd  .;S...R.l.....+.
00000ce0: 0b46 0ba7 b575 4498 1bf2 7db8 c64a 32f4  .F...uD...}..J2.
00000cf0: baa4 307f 2951 4ad9 fc73 53ca 3a0b 1562  ..0.)QJ..sS.:..b
00000d00: fa75 aa47 6f61 a4c8 cf1f 8f55 30c6 c562  .u.Goa.....U0..b
00000d10: b41f af41 c66d ebc6 9853 25cb b850 3d03  ...A.m...S%..P=.
00000d20: 3392 1cd6 2f59 2e89 f918 fde7 36a3 1424  3.../Y......6..$
00000d30: 6eab 9e3e a1c6 91a5 bf5e e320 a047 252d  n..>.....^. .G%-
00000d40: a4d9 2bd1 8048 d126 bda5 8e50 ea16 838e  ..+..H.&...P....
00000d50: 80a5 9b6c 86ec 6e59 906e 5654 b672 b03b  ...l..nY.nVT.r.;
00000d60: accf 2bb2 a1ed da06 4ddc 65c8 6cf7 0d05  ..+.....M.e.l...
00000d70: fe11 9aea 8ef9 dd41 b531 a234 7aca 790d  .......A.1.4z.y.
00000d80: ff15 1d8f acfe e628 0c9d 761c 609d 9992  .......(..v.`...
00000d90: ff56 f7ce 1ac9 b847 ea95 583f 50b6 2195  .V.....G..X?P.!.
00000da0: f203 89bc 9751 044c 1fb0 6f37 de74 4849  .....Q.L..o7.tHI
00000db0: 2169 ef09 556a 5b42 eaf7 ff41 7844 6568  !i..Uj[B...AxDeh
00000dc0: 7364 8e61 8a81 0263 1a56 a1ca 893f 4dec  sd.a...c.V...?M.
00000dd0: 4f23 e0a7 fa5e a8e8 638f 73f5 3ff3 d87c  O#...^..c.s.?..|
00000de0: c331 076a 96e7 8332 790c 8583 8f0b 1021  .1.j...2y......!
00000df0: f89c b9a4 e072 ca0f 5a1f 9a53 f15b 3c7f  .....r..Z..S.[<.
00000e00: 796d 22e5 0f39 9227 a006 0cc5 d689 698a  ym"..9.'......i.
00000e10: 5df0 44ff a75a 4324 455e 5ba7 f7a0 90bc  ].D..ZC$E^[.....
00000e20: ded1 18dc 827d bd77 3fc5 9248 85d2 17d4  .....}.w?..H....
00000e30: e45f 58e6 9eee c4fb c646 3eee a0e4 827b  ._X......F>....{
00000e40: cbf3 b7a2 6d07 d795 c70d 3859 0f1b 3fbe  ....m.....8Y..?.
00000e50: e454 aeaf 400c df98 1413 9c7f d0b5 3467  .T..@.........4g
00000e60: ad84 abcd 1dc6 21d7 42b9 a26b 38b1 07aa  ......!.B..k8...
00000e70: 8999 c2c5 29d8 f44a d3b6 52f3 19f4 7261  ....)..J..R...ra
00000e80: 7873 a5b3 d95a 3189 5b2e 057d 7048 3535  xs...Z1.[..}pH55
00000e90: 2276 df0f 8fcb 3daf 271b fc24 845f cb12  "v....=.'..$._..
00000ea0: ecae f8b5 2705 e5c6 0446 1846 c2bb fb22  ....'....F.F..."
00000eb0: a5ff 4d46 a3ed 32d8 2cb5 e1b6 6baf 812c  ..MF..2.,...k..,
00000ec0: 1292 2202 1b0a 99db 0730 19db a191 cf52  .."......0.....R
00000ed0: 037d 8f07 d5fb b9cd 4a9c 0b5f 9930 3bb9  .}......J.._.0;.
00000ee0: 30de af83 3736 def6 beb8 ee12 badc 01e6  0...76..........
00000ef0: 860b 4fa1 e5a7 840b 9a54 e0c4 a0dc 9840  ..O......T.....@
00000f00: 70b8 6cfb 2ed1 922e 9128 8e9d 70c2 a712  p.l......(..p...
00000f10: 8bf5 8509 b12c 8871 4600 a219 3b9a a7b5  .....,.qF...;...
00000f20: c11a 7f9b c840 fdc9 9509 ea13 85bb ada3  .....@..........
00000f30: 0468 7b16 e58f d1e2 e0c9 b21b 3c56 f3ea  .h{.........<V..
00000f40: b54a 5dd8 4f0f ab69 eeef 4288 59b9 ad46  .J].O..i..B.Y..F
00000f50: a2b3 e59a a85c 37f0 6fe2 d20f f8ff f42b  .....\7.o......+
00000f60: 7aa2 4466 10f7 1b05 913e b0a9 1c21 cd6b  z.Df.....>...!.k
00000f70: e52d a39f 2504 c16a bd29 59dc ce44 f4b8  .-..%..j.)Y..D..
00000f80: a24f 33f1 6876 2f6e 0044 09a0 361c 6465  .O3.hv/n.D..6.de
00000f90: 9d60 9c4d 009c 4acb 9c17 6671 0e85 d855  .`.M..J...fq...U
00000fa0: 8d75 68fe 2888 ba21 acf4 1775 2a4e 8b48  .uh.(..!...u*N.H
00000fb0: 9de4 ce8f a90b 8f2e 5282 7bbb e0c2 3a04  ........R.{...:.
00000fc0: e96e 2448 9c1e 10fb 5f7a 3d1a d98d 079e  .n$H...._z=.....
00000fd0: aead 78d6 e47c 6fc3 d1cc 447e 1771 16ba  ..x..|o...D~.q..
00000fe0: acb2 b1b0 50db 88f1 b721 977b 1063 6058  ....P....!.{.c`X
00000ff0: 11b4 8e59 c1ec fbf3 dce2 d673 5c53 3c47  ...Y.......s\S<G
00001000: 817f e4b6 e7f1 6579 7866 2ba5 39d8 ae5d  ......eyxf+.9..]
00001010: 6d64 657b 1943 8cf1 8f39 6830 d71f ef6e  mde{.C...9h0...n
00001020: 566a a78f 65b8 3004 84a4 db3c 8cbb 0294  Vj..e.0....<....
00001030: 134c 5488 9bdd f57a ea9d 8a9a 2ebe c6b0  .LT....z........
00001040: 166a 5e85 a73e d7f0 6406 44d8 f437 7cb2  .j^..>..d.D..7|.
00001050: c698 f1de 55c6 38e6 39b1 d148 7ca1 de13  ....U.8.9..H|...
00001060: 8f7f cc02 9ed9 3c6d d5c5 4d2d 1a39 e4a3  ......<m..M-.9..
00001070: e765 4e56 bdcc f066 cdbf 8fe6 4785 1ea2  .eNV...f....G...
00001080: c89c 5bc7 1c4c f5d0 aa19 2d7e 1863 697c  ..[..L....-~.ci|
00001090: 4455 219c 21a3 66b2 4291 8887 ed5a 57cc  DU!.!.f.B....ZW.
000010a0: 3658 ce5a a35d cefe 9012 8ef4 5aec cf83  6X.Z.]......Z...
000010b0: 308a a043 f967 fb1b 8c81 ad3a 68a3 6e63  0..C.g.....:h.nc
000010c0: 19be c451 8202 db3a aa7f 590e 8077 d7b9  ...Q...:..Y..w..
000010d0: 850e 4697 14ec fe49 6da7 afc3 eb7e 2991  ..F....Im....~).
000010e0: 4a0a c210 c64d 7efd 2e69 ffa3 bd27 4d71  J....M~..i...'Mq
000010f0: fb84 b761 0759 cbbb cb4e b6f0 f0a2 0f1a  ...a.Y...N......
00001100: aa99 5913 cefd 6136 3400 31f5 6da7 e2bb  ..Y...a64.1.m...
00001110: d479 10e4 8ba9 b65c e84a 818d 0f61 7f63  .y.....\.J...a.c
00001120: 133f 0da3 5386 b8ee 8ab5 26c6 355f 2f91  .?..S.....&.5_/.
00001130: 4083 e934 3f77 cfcc 1722 0b53 4801 2e42  @..4?w...".SH..B
00001140: 3aec a3ae dbab 2740 e624 6638 fd56 753c  :.....'@.$f8.Vu<
00001150: 8697 6278 482f e91a 9cf9 d450 9612 d720  ..bxH/.....P... 
00001160: 9a15 f12f 214d c0ae aae7 2967 1ef0 4a5b  .../!M....)g..J[
00001170: 04d2 46e7 485d 5dbd e5f5 ee05 b19a db0d  ..F.H]].........
00001180: a8e4 db24 54e8 85a5 59b4 8089 310b bb60  ...$T...Y...1..`
00001190: aaa2 cb89 bf49 3d4e 13ee 92c7 515a 81f5  .....I=N....QZ..
000011a0: 53da f737 5b60 8022 d1c4 f79c b540 818f  S..7[`.".....@..
000011b0: 3931 a7b6 ca56 43dc 07b9 e3b2 e1ab 6852  91...VC.......hR
000011c0: 7d4e ac70 38ec 8df4 97a2 c936 e533 a84a  }N.p8......6.3.J
000011d0: d6ef a80e c571 16c2 0d28 9ee5 1bb3 7e23  .....q...(....~#
000011e0: 43a3 69c5 d0d0 65cb e381 0320 a41e a099  C.i...e.... ....
000011f0: 97ec f6b4 c694 c8fc de70 5f9e 74a6 50da  .........p_.t.P.
00001200: 34d3 0951 c730 b214 a4a7 823d 1fa4 af97  4..Q.0.....=....
00001210: 5f32 ba7b ddf8 4ecf 9b7d 86e2 da9a 6379  _2.{..N..}....cy
00001220: 5324 3736 7fb3 4fc3 a000 cd85 37b0 05b8  S$76..O.....7...
00001230: dab4 7290 2e0f 7615 af53 e065 5c7b 73cb  ..r...v..S.e\{s.
00001240: 20f7 1884 4997 c8d8 c889 b58e ed9e 114c   ...I..........L
00001250: f02f c231 4f16 5b13 e133 784d 2f07 5ea1  ./.1O.[..3xM/.^.
00001260: 3e43 a593 46d9 cf8d 7a24 203d 5ddd b091  >C..F...z$ =]...
00001270: f715 2633 2a43 b026 eb5a 0e3e 3609 0d89  ..&3*C.&.Z.>6...
00001280: c0f3 074d def5 fb59 d4bd 1b17 07a7 ee5d  ...M...Y.......]
00001290: 3d87 0b55 7f09 8732 997d 29e7 a2d6 00d7  =..U...2.}).....
000012a0: 3dc0 c578 0557 1213 95e4 3e25 d3d3 5223  =..x.W....>%..R#
000012b0: 3b53 a961 5b40 6949 b975 c79f 6c3c 5237  ;S.a[@iI.u..l<R7
000012c0: 8e3e cf6a 26dd bff1 148c fd99 fd97 210e  .>.j&.........!.
000012d0: 8c81 f84d 3635 fd5e d778 c2ab e3ba 44e9  ...M65.^.x....D.
000012e0: a911 11c9 7025 a1ba cdb9 a866 24ac 8d1c  ....p%.....f$...
000012f0: b109 82b1 8011 9eb2 7a33 12f5 3a83 8aa0  ........z3..:...
00001300: 1ef0 6e03 26fd 76ae e004 93e5 429e c41d  ..n.&.v.....B...
00001310: 5207 8708 dc3c a765 b741 3cf4 61c5 759f  R....<.e.A<.a.u.
00001320: 578d 4853 5020 7a01 b993 7481 de92 0d0d  W.HSP z...t.....
00001330: b316 deb9 42c5 4ce8 0478 c478 b3d6 8a97  ....B.L..x.x....
00001340: 7572 57d5 23dd 4d93 43f6 4664 2688 53c4  urW.#.M.C.Fd&.S.
00001350: f13e eabe ba29 471b c341 c19b 7c34 936d  .>...)G..A..|4.m
00001360: f50c 2f70 d77c 5574 1af0 610f cca0 9e8b  ../p.|Ut..a.....
00001370: b0a5 56a8 2d8b 828d 7e11 884b 246b 0777  ..V.-...~..K$k.w
00001380: c11b d7c8 9cf5 77f0 58e5 fdfa 7ea3 22b2  ......w.X...~.".
00001390: cb60 a161 c051 f742 a423 8da7 e911 bdbb  .`.a.Q.B.#......
000013a0: 59eb 57ef a08a ba8c fda0 6891 f4b6 74ed  Y.W.......h...t.
000013b0: 9801 b9f7 1c24 5e43 0212 6e43 d506 4af5  .....$^C..nC..J.
000013c0: 62e3 3cdc a272 4791 efa4 bb4c 11da 5208  b.<..rG....L..R.
000013d0: d6f6 7942 a047 2048 5aca b12b 0f38 7236  ..yB.G HZ..+.8r6
000013e0: f7e1 7d25 1be3 07f8 2701 bed6 5c8b 7f99  ..}%....'...\...
000013f0: 6edb 9ed2 32db 214b ed2b 19aa 2583 c338  n...2.!K.+..%..8
00001400: 10d8 f948 9822 0058 e046 5ba3 f8ed cf4e  ...H.".X.F[....N
00001410: 4a38 8ae4 9eeb 5446 ce08 a6b9 fc22 ad73  J8....TF.....".s
00001420: 642f 7096 8431 bf6d 9e3a adcd 35c8 6c2e  d/p..1.m.:..5.l.
00001430: b8b9 d631 e8cb f2b6 e219 2d12 1942 fad4  ...1......-..B..
00001440: a117 0a06 231b 21e9 735c 8a1a ae33 7bb5  ....#.!.s\...3{.
00001450: 47d0 1b02 618d 8e90 acdd 63b6 8b87 609e  G...a.....c...`.
00001460: 99cc fb76 ddb7 29bd 6636 8add 8af3 24d4  ...v..).f6....$.
00001470: 8ad2 7e99 b84b 7cdf 5224 9c18 f98d 5a1b  ..~..K|.R$....Z.
00001480: f426 8713 553d 86dc 7990 ae7d 13f7 d2a2  .&..U=..y..}....
00001490: 04eb 74da 7327 a77f 2826 fa8f cf5b 19b1  ..t.s'..(&...[..
000014a0: c7ea efbd 7009 5e20 ae10 3637 28d1 accb  ....p.^ ..67(...
000014b0: 173d 288c 2ee3 fa0c d411 5aa7 8c39 9dfa  .=(.......Z..9..
000014c0: ba7d 39ce 1888 2a46 a7ef 16b9 e9b1 4445  .}9...*F......DE
000014d0: 803b 0fe9 e63d efb0 acb2 5b13 09f3 c0e2  .;...=....[.....
000014e0: ba8b 05da 4f06 523e 57e4 6759 c269 e06d  ....O.R>W.gY.i.m
000014f0: 235a 55ae 38fe 0e37 d5be aaf8 dfe0 003b  #ZU.8..7.......;
00001500: 28ce 2239 f17a 7519 a36a bfb3 7701 7387  (."9.zu..j..w.s.
00001510: b233 9a36 2263 b669 a625 01c2 bc2a 3556  .3.6"c.i.%...*5V
00001520: 87b2 0ab9 5633 9e2a 601d 959f 3ca0 57d3  ....V3.*`...<.W.
00001530: a825 ea82 dca8 875a 806b db58 017e 27d6  .%.....Z.k.X.~'.
00001540: 4b36 a1b6 605b d114 d15d efb3 5b1a f4f5  K6..`[...]..[...
00001550: 8d81 85e4 1b5e 6ecc e650 7825 a442 fad5  .....^n..Px%.B..
00001560: 1637 d53b f1b3 ab70 b233 5aae bede 130d  .7.;...p.3Z.....
00001570: b5a9 5746 7afb 6c1e 47ce c20b 6e1a 8e88  ..WFz.l.G...n...
00001580: 4815 5832 17b7 f9c7 a71e 9045 d225 97c1  H.X2.......E.%..
00001590: dfb6 c6e9 4ba5 40bf 79b2 0b6b c8d2 ca97  ....K.@.y..k....
000015a0: b23d ac32 a78d 3e24 aee8 1412 0588 c790  .=.2..>$........
000015b0: 4c0d f334 46c5 077b 435b 1a0d d304 11b8  L..4F..{C[......
000015c0: 7098 2ab2 ef57 ab93 fc6d 6333 3023 edbd  p.*..W...mc30#..
000015d0: 9628 68bf 24bc e607 dd60 faa7 e603 93bd  .(h.$....`......
000015e0: 1145 f202 708a 0587 d35b 609e a2f0 6d2b  .E..p....[`...m+
000015f0: 28aa 16ed 250d 7bfa bea2 4efd 284d d13f  (...%.{...N.(M.?
00001600: 15dd 123b f9d8 cc84 10a5 41de 638a 38f6  ...;......A.c.8.
00001610: bd65 188e fd49 9ed1 2bba e303 4620 1d79  .e...I..+...F .y
00001620: 234f 9bec e35e 494b 15a9 c43d a2f8 90e9  #O...^IK...=....
00001630: de2e 51a9 130c f976 ed53 2047 d911 6fb4  ..Q....v.S G..o.
00001640: 6417 d5fd b1ca e6e8 40bd 9ecb 5816 8a3e  d.......@...X..>
00001650: 7d3f 1725 f280 dafb af5e 5c08 4e7e 13b3  }?.%.....^\.N~..
00001660: 79dd 2e9b 3495 2774 c4f4 2d2b 1cb5 fa78  y...4.'t..-+...x
00001670: e40a 3d09 00b8 5161 bad2 0798 4d24 991a  ..=...Qa....M$..
00001680: c780 ea49 7401 a7b7 481f 0777 7187 e2f9  ...It...H..wq...
00001690: 51dc bf1a b802 ddbc c9ef c2fb 4177 9fc5  Q...........Aw..
000016a0: 66db 6511 f87c 8f74 132e 1119 52ca ab59  f.e..|.t....R..Y
000016b0: 2623 855b 520c 7955 facd e594 b89d aea4  &#.[R.yU........
000016c0: eb85 8776 178d 6ed1 dfbd f2fa 071e 8ff7  ...v..n.........
000016d0: fbcb c7b9 1e85 1eb3 8b17 7fb8 4f4b 1dc1  ............OK..
000016e0: e8fd 23b5 eecb bdf7 308a 83c2 ab69 66bd  ..#.....0....if.
000016f0: a40c 6737 a9a1 2985 1911 21ab f08e e321  ..g7..)...!....!
00001700: 57cf fcdb ca0c 8d79 4b63 c3cb 3a57 aff9  W......yKc..:W..
00001710: 32e0 aaa5 920b adce 0520 9f93 d1d8 2cf7  2........ ....,.
00001720: 0800 a954 be57 93b5 d932 b222 f1fc 3e7a  ...T.W...2."..>z
00001730: efd8 145c 8884 b607 e9b3 d538 5a8f 57de  ...\.......8Z.W.
00001740: d732 f554 f139 fc62 1d40 3e25 d4a4 c856  .2.T.9.b.@>%...V
00001750: 6621 4985 38bb 19c9 c4bc 246d 9387 e193  f!I.8.....$m....
00001760: bba3 4d5a 6172 e18c fdc0 c02b 3f8e ef13  ..MZar.....+?...
00001770: d85a 5adc 7d90 9bea ea98 ac21 e67f de34  .ZZ.}......!...4
00001780: 396f e260 8af6 f386 cfc0 4369 d45d f193  9o.`......Ci.]..
00001790: a7d6 2034 6658 84ad ae2c ea95 8b79 3bbc  .. 4fX...,...y;.
000017a0: f901 acee 5e5e b958 e320 593f c02d a849  ....^^.X. Y?.-.I
000017b0: f947 8bef 16cb d284 8f32 937f fb56 d56d  .G.......2...V.m
000017c0: 554c ef61 fcd9 3015 56fd c042 0ba9 a19e  UL.a..0.V..B....
000017d0: be9f 8224 8cd5 21ef 1a3f 3764 c4e4 4013  ...$..!..?7d..@.
000017e0: 905f 2b10 f88d 7ec7 bca6 bb1f 5ce7 adf9  ._+...~.....\...
000017f0: 40a5 0ea1 2884 9ee7 7ce8 88d8 8325 1b96  @...(...|....%..
00001800: dc71 34de 38ec a2d8 07e3 4d41 4baa 0cbe  .q4.8.....MAK...
00001810: 3fb5 b98c df9b 762b b017 ec20 a617 6b88  ?.....v+... ..k.
00001820: 1124 6e18 e6c3 c7ad 0155 2bff 464b ce7e  .$n......U+.FK.~
00001830: cc0f 13dd eaa3 67b0 03b0 f178 3fbb 0bd2  ......g....x?...
00001840: f246 9a57 3a0e 8bbe 447e d6eb 58b6 8c56  .F.W:...D~..X..V
00001850: f3c9 491e e726 7265 5be1 e14d b218 af1b  ..I..&re[..M....
00001860: 609e f5fd 1384 9068 5f3e 65be 7dc8 7384  `......h_>e.}.s.
00001870: 9408 6b73 574b 78c1 2ad6 e62d d242 b717  ..ksWKx.*..-.B..
00001880: f569 e190 3a1d 7299 ffac d8cf b5d7 35bc  .i..:.r.......5.
00001890: b16b 46ef fbc1 5edc e4e2 e22d 46a9 e534  .kF...^....-F..4
000018a0: 25f3 5c76 4263 079b eda4 f131 616e ecf0  %.\vBc.....1an..
000018b0: df86 568f 855c 8f64 662e aa66 81dd 3ac6  ..V..\.df..f..:.
000018c0: 1650 8711 7673 9ce8 cc47 01da 362b 7314  .P..vs...G..6+s.
000018d0: 5e56 733e 7ecc 9dc7 fe38 a2c2 cf55 74e5  ^Vs>~....8...Ut.
000018e0: 2091 e4bc a19b df94 6ce4 48d9 946f 5f5b   .......l.H..o_[
000018f0: 739b 2772 f6d5 c95d a999 1cb7 68c9 5fc2  s.'r...]....h._.
00001900: 710d 9f7f 972e 6523 ca15 3163 086c 24f8  q.....e#..1c.l$.
00001910: 06d9 4c89 fe77 3529 d074 d4f7 bac3 debe  ..L..w5).t......
00001920: 4522 096b 3ee8 bd15 91ef ccec f21a 0c8b  E".k>...........
00001930: e0a2 0abd 7bba b5a3 2c6c fdef 3e32 ae83  ....{...,l..>2..
00001940: 4bb0 7480 286b b0e9 13f4 e6af 8930 cf27  K.t.(k.......0.'
00001950: a5e7 9c4a 3a37 1093 8dd1 5ad8 f26e f8b3  ...J:7....Z..n..
00001960: ff0a 2051 3790 283f cee5 a1f9 ab0d b6ac  .. Q7.(?........
00001970: e7bd 1a6a d474 ccf3 4523 210a 758a 802c  ...j.t..E#!.u..,
00001980: f8c4 0016 7144 179b 5849 cc5d 1570 cafa  ....qD..XI.].p..
00001990: 66ea b8c7 533e 245e 9243 76b4 0d02 52c2  f...S>$^.Cv...R.
000019a0: 42e0 be5e 0256 ce5e 6156 58cb 6582 2f6a  B..^.V.^aVX.e./j
000019b0: 8ac0 5c65 a4a9 0198 359b 5183 4166 796d  ..\e....5.Q.Afym
000019c0: f35c 48b3 2286 9e09 9a0d e166 6ab5 e61e  .\H."......fj...
000019d0: f4c9 4baf bb45 9cc4 e083 17d7 5aac e69f  ..K..E......Z...
000019e0: a6d4 187a 169e ae47 75f0 0024 f07f f2c4  ...z...Gu..$....
000019f0: 6369 e6d0 02d6 1968 500b 0013 1fcf 9968  ci.....hP......h
00001a00: c64c 6380 8b58 5dcc ba5d 547a 9637 ff45  .Lc..X]..]Tz.7.E
00001a10: eaa4 9b9d 952f 04ba 39c8 8226 ce9f 74fe  ...../..9..&..t.
00001a20: e618 d3e2 328e a166 1762 0957 1c61 fac1  ....2..f.b.W.a..
00001a30: 3ba2 b84f 01b6 3b1d 3394 2992 3586 120b  ;..O..;.3.).5...
00001a40: 2d5a 7119 32c2 421b 7fd8 b023 64e0 c756  -Zq.2.B....#d..V
00001a50: 7bb3 5ba1 76fe 9970 a39a cde7 5351 3131  {.[.v..p....SQ11
00001a60: 428e 7c27 055d fdd8 be22 6ad9 8376 8424  B.|'.]..."j..v.$
00001a70: 3606 c3ec dcd3 ca92 6f24 4f84 4cd0 3bc5  6.......o$O.L.;.
00001a80: b001 7426 df49 eb58 b74a ba36 2388 c3aa  ..t&.I.X.J.6#...
00001a90: 083e a652 6081 3a05 2441 80e8 5ed7 1f23  .>.R`.:.$A..^..#
00001aa0: f14b 082c ba42 1beb fb72 b841 6ceb d99f  .K.,.B...r.Al...
00001ab0: 62eb 19b5 0044 ea18 43b9 3179 5496 1381  b....D..C.1yT...
00001ac0: c8af 4e0f 026a 5885 0314 645b 14a4 d93b  ..N..jX...d[...;
00001ad0: 57cc 7e1d a4cc dcd4 7fde f720 1c3b 2548  W.~........ .;%H
00001ae0: 5dd1 54d3 d818 31af 71d4 9f6c 4e34 ed7c  ].T...1.q..lN4.|
00001af0: e2a9 f572 3965 ffc3 23ed 2fe5 c944 e7dc  ...r9e..#./..D..
00001b00: b622 e609 5c96 76cb 3a3c ecce 548c 097f  ."..\.v.:<..T...
00001b10: da84 f881 1177 abe9 8ccf 85a2 eaa6 b63f  .....w.........?
00001b20: e651 594f b4ce 4759 6acc 98c5 2835 a41d  .QYO..GYj...(5..
00001b30: 060a c49d 2851 29fb b727 f9c8 61a3 2b1d  ....(Q)..'..a.+.
00001b40: ecde d381 8ffa ce86 61d0 ec6c 8beb ac54  ........a..l...T
00001b50: e51f 0337 e0d7 3f95 949e a404 da0e c3ca  ...7..?.........
00001b60: 954c 47c2 472d 5ed1 f2fa 2602 fc4f 2abf  .LG.G-^...&..O*.
00001b70: e528 e598 80d3 8869 9a52 e08f ade4 6c0c  .(.....i.R....l.
00001b80: 5706 2ee4 ed0f 6130 e1b2 726e e429 52a9  W.....a0..rn.)R.
00001b90: f4cd e38b aad8 f187 9a0b e584 49ca 71a1  ............I.q.
00001ba0: 7e3d 7901 e1e8 a75b 9c8f b6c3 279a 6fa7  ~=y....[....'.o.
00001bb0: 845e 9b68 2f63 2505 2d00 16ef fb95 8bcd  .^.h/c%.-.......
00001bc0: 6d1a ba08 c064 90e7 906b a6c2 f9f1 f8fb  m....d...k......
00001bd0: 678a 8903 8e2f 9a0d c5c1 ac14 0ba9 2a0a  g..../........*.
00001be0: a188 15bb 0c6b b952 abdc c152 aff4 aa26  .....k.R...R...&
00001bf0: 3e0a 3cbb a6a5 ca8a 458e e45f 50ac 97bb  >.<.....E.._P...
00001c00: 7645 23a4 bb65 2f54 d093 a381 cd21 f46c  vE#..e/T.....!.l
00001c10: 4733 5d30 ed55 7f72 40fa 14b7            G3]0.U.r@...
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Sledgehammer.  It looks like Sledgehammer code is compressed Mathematica code (with a Braille veneer) -- is that right?

Comment: Yes. 10 more to go...

Comment: 10 more? I must have missed something.

Comment: @MitchellSpector Merely "Yes." with a space is 5 chars, and comments must be at least 15, so I needed padding test. I decided to use the "10 more to go..." message.

Comment: Ahhh, I missed that.

Comment: Can you improve this by doing the same sort of adaptive arithmetic coding, but predicting each 3-base sequence from the previous 3-base sequence (rather than predicting each base from the previous base, which I gather is what you're doing?).  (There are only 64 different 3-base sequences.)

Comment: @MitchellSpector I tried predicting the next character from the 2 previous chars, and I get 7197 bytes if the probabilities are dynamically learned rather than hardcoded. It sounds unlikely that the results will be significantly better if I used 3-base sequences as basic blocks (unless if I hardcoded the probabilities; then that would almost match the entropy, but the code size would increase a lot). I suspect that it's possible to use the Burrows-Wheeler transform here, but I still have to figure out how it works and how to implement it.

Answer (score 23):

## bash + `flif-tools`, 40+1+7359 = 7400 bytes

First, I noticed that the probabilities of various letters weren't evenly distributed, and I thought I should use some kind of arithmetic coding. Then I realised that this awesome image format, about which I remember that it uses some super-complicated kind of arithmetic coding, can be used  to compress the SARS-CoV-2 genome.

```
flif -d f .pgm
cat .pgm|tr -cd ACUG
```

Requires a file named `f` in the current directory, with the following contents (it's a 29903x1 image):

```
00000000: 464c 4946 3131 81e9 4e00 0041 7ef2 f1e6  FLIF11..N..A~...
00000010: 7012 b5f1 79f4 99da 8f57 1fd4 eb3e dca1  p...y....W...>..
00000020: 4b84 7263 bc59 a96d 1e17 5f91 3326 aee5  K.rc.Y.m.._.3&..
00000030: 2bd0 faa0 43f5 5613 362f bac7 a79c b96b  +...C.V.6/.....k
00000040: 54f1 76f1 d0b3 ecc6 cbbf e7dc 3147 2233  T.v.........1G"3
00000050: 6fd6 4ba1 ed75 5031 748c 71e8 7b8e 0852  o.K..uP1t.q.{..R
00000060: 1218 e539 5991 ce94 c750 ed10 1f9c cff3  ...9Y....P......
00000070: bc6e 66af 70fe 256c 368c fd5d d17f d8ed  .nf.p.%l6..]....
00000080: 893c 1c1d d02e 863b 9a74 a1d2 3a14 96bb  .<.....;.t..:...
00000090: aefe d54f 2d65 6660 cc0d ab9b cc1f 5edb  ...O-ef`......^.
000000a0: 7cd6 de58 9a2f e729 95b3 ba7a 7022 b237  |..X./.)...zp".7
000000b0: c828 3407 2404 1ce5 c21e 9b31 aae0 670c  .(4.$......1..g.
000000c0: 4c3c 7266 c70e 014a a7e8 495f ea33 f8be  L<rf...J..I_.3..
000000d0: 7a94 0a64 331e e59a a0bc d1e9 3151 8465  z..d3.......1Q.e
000000e0: be91 5f5a 6725 d496 3366 cc44 2e8a 46df  .._Zg%..3f.D..F.
000000f0: 791e 6048 944a 4700 cb48 e986 b0b0 657b  y.`H.JG..H....e{
00000100: a77d efac 6bb2 d669 1403 90a2 d4c2 df32  .}..k..i.......2
00000110: 6a62 ae22 ea05 a751 8696 9343 aef8 5256  jb."...Q...C..RV
00000120: 8b5b e09d 7c80 e05b f748 968b fb6b 1a36  .[..|..[.H...k.6
00000130: 7e9b 9784 4dc9 bfab 8871 374a d9bd a9c7  ~...M....q7J....
00000140: 5245 39cb c5f6 3ada 8d86 e72d affb 473f  RE9...:....-..G?
00000150: 0065 19ee 5517 4481 81aa 9c72 70b5 17b3  .e..U.D....rp...
00000160: 1341 b678 22e2 c84b 2df5 faa3 0584 22b8  .A.x"..K-.....".
00000170: 3cc4 5337 7b9f 443e e455 e66b 68f5 9caf  <.S7{.D>.U.kh...
00000180: db3f d0cc dba9 18ce bb67 b14e bd41 306e  .?.......g.N.A0n
00000190: 9829 3506 9b25 544a 4aab 0ecc d64a 3136  .)5..%TJJ....J16
000001a0: 50c6 962b 635a 7502 fd81 45ab bb1f d1b4  P..+cZu...E.....
000001b0: 2eef 658a 7b35 2af7 3166 bb89 8adb 6f52  ..e.{5*.1f....oR
000001c0: 58dc 2b8c ae57 3886 eeff 0975 e141 d98f  X.+..W8....u.A..
000001d0: eb65 84c9 a19d 4bf3 b111 8c02 ba9b b366  .e....K........f
000001e0: 481a b148 529c 1bde 71c5 c393 7062 9918  H..HR...q...pb..
000001f0: 5bab 356e 8b85 f9d8 66b5 75f7 99b1 f938  [.5n....f.u....8
00000200: 52b4 87d0 ada1 af71 80b1 bfad c797 e508  R......q........
00000210: 1683 40cc ae1c 81d3 17e4 4a50 31ba 8077  ..@.......JP1..w
00000220: cc79 ad9b 77c5 6d8a 6275 3a02 5fe0 4c6d  .y..w.m.bu:._.Lm
00000230: 878e 144a 40e5 c3d8 24f3 fe4e 9c9f 9820  ...J@...$..N... 
00000240: be90 81c9 c4c8 dd16 e678 887c 3ba0 8633  .........x.|;..3
00000250: 4572 4533 6254 1ead bd0a c17a ca9a 4220  ErE3bT.....z..B 
00000260: eb9c 614f da8c 21e3 1ea4 f269 fa2f c146  ..aO..!....i./.F
00000270: ef5f fee2 9aad badf 35a7 9454 f7f6 e004  ._......5..T....
00000280: 5fec b825 c2ad 49f7 eb07 be5d 0aef f53b  _..%..I....]...;
00000290: 63f5 6681 844d a955 8fe7 9ad7 ba8d 490f  c.f..M.U......I.
000002a0: 3203 f35e 9fa5 07f1 c976 5b51 08f3 c89e  2..^.....v[Q....
000002b0: d836 9be5 7367 e30c b466 817a b60b 160f  .6..sg...f.z....
000002c0: b874 901b 3c4a b10c a480 c359 43b2 9cb3  .t..<J.....YC...
000002d0: 38fe 8285 6807 7fa7 a8bc 1d25 3bd8 0713  8...h......%;...
000002e0: e4a0 2b0a f89d 2545 ce8d f9d1 28b8 75a8  ..+...%E....(.u.
000002f0: 57f8 2ee4 8e8d c698 45eb 96c3 04dc 5604  W.......E.....V.
00000300: 96b2 b5ee 4ed0 5536 1075 97e6 dbf6 2454  ....N.U6.u....$T
00000310: c73c b356 6724 e2de 69d9 bcdd 9a20 9814  .<.Vg$..i.... ..
00000320: 96f8 5418 7035 9ced 6756 5db1 0e01 e874  ..T.p5..gV]....t
00000330: 5ff7 86c9 3157 0c4e 185a 3cfb e68e 3289  _...1W.N.Z<...2.
00000340: 3a4d e961 fad7 1936 c71a 0116 b7df be82  :M.a...6........
00000350: e477 9d6e 84b5 88eb e947 8071 ab8a 896b  .w.n.....G.q...k
00000360: fc2b d99d 67e6 3463 3c00 b119 49df c559  .+..g.4c<...I..Y
00000370: 832c 9f53 7f71 655a a7e4 ea7d 301d 86fc  .,.S.qeZ...}0...
00000380: b2e1 cdd5 c06c 00a4 c0eb a479 aa35 4b49  .....l.....y.5KI
00000390: 6f6d 7f0e 1981 ca10 6fb0 9b53 a889 4ffb  om......o..S..O.
000003a0: 0923 5345 4464 9d7d 7bc0 4c22 83e8 69fb  .#SEDd.}{.L"..i.
000003b0: 89df d7d2 c1a9 f7e6 21ad 75a4 1200 1d8f  ........!.u.....
000003c0: d518 d8c4 cbd3 0097 bbb6 495a 4a73 9b55  ..........IZJs.U
000003d0: e159 44f5 32aa ac14 2a29 9662 f6dc afbd  .YD.2...*).b....
000003e0: 92d0 61da de21 ed63 64cc 7b11 94ec 91c3  ..a..!.cd.{.....
000003f0: 10ff 316f 49f9 52c1 4a12 66e6 4104 d699  ..1oI.R.J.f.A...
00000400: 8196 a64e e594 71ae bb76 bd0f 0ae6 7c62  ...N..q..v....|b
00000410: 0fea b4c4 c01f fb55 a0ce 5677 017f db45  .......U..Vw...E
00000420: cbbe da6f 6a37 be75 2e6a 9a9d 797a 7ee5  ...oj7.u.j..yz~.
00000430: bc72 a10b 6e70 f25c 5e44 5834 c37d 0747  .r..np.\^DX4.}.G
00000440: bc7a 3abd 794a 9c05 8a4e 62c8 397c a279  .z:.yJ...Nb.9|.y
00000450: 21ad 285b ec73 b749 a7b3 7d43 8b8b 8f87  !.([.s.I..}C....
00000460: 2711 744a 6abe 1a75 e872 4c06 17d5 6807  '.tJj..u.rL...h.
00000470: 71f9 9dab 30dc 839c 83c1 7b6f f6fe 923b  q...0.....{o...;
00000480: 2cfe 5d3f 62de 1e1a 9969 ce73 84eb 0c24  ,.]?b....i.s...$
00000490: 3934 59a5 fe9d 6093 a523 d20d fbb0 b500  94Y...`..#......
000004a0: b9cd 08aa dfc0 76d5 d4d7 db42 88a2 d33f  ......v....B...?
000004b0: 351f f9f8 7d8e 6987 da3e 8bce b5bb 042a  5...}.i..>.....*
000004c0: c085 c0ec aea3 be86 db4a 8f1c bd58 2be2  .........J...X+.
000004d0: 4586 f743 eaef 8a80 cf07 27e7 0159 c070  E..C......'..Y.p
000004e0: cf94 4d56 45e1 a0c0 7837 e081 16ea 6566  ..MVE...x7....ef
000004f0: 4f89 7bf8 7160 a851 e2cf 8396 05a9 fc37  O.{.q`.Q.......7
00000500: 6ed8 69ee f651 aa56 0660 18ec 0fd0 e948  n.i..Q.V.`.....H
00000510: ee27 6c35 620f e472 0c04 7902 35d5 58cd  .'l5b..r..y.5.X.
00000520: d117 d1ab 16f2 f89e 6210 fdfa 300a ffa5  ........b...0...
00000530: 4f0e 60be 7516 69c0 22de 46cd eb3e e60b  O.`.u.i.".F..>..
00000540: 6f00 9737 a429 0c99 22ce 5f0f 1b20 56c7  o..7.).."._.. V.
00000550: f1a2 d5b8 d782 98fd 521e 68a1 fd73 4f56  ........R.h..sOV
00000560: 50de ec30 4d39 8e5f f4f8 f153 d448 13cd  P..0M9._...S.H..
00000570: 29d5 2aa7 d4fa e6b1 16d3 ef68 9a13 8c22  ).*........h..."
00000580: afcf dcc7 9e86 cb81 a943 6cab f850 ed0a  .........Cl..P..
00000590: b258 8dd0 ad7d 5f8f a7cd aa7e 84f9 a1a5  .X...}_....~....
000005a0: 1f70 ee1a ec0b d963 3e95 5439 1c77 588b  .p.....c>.T9.wX.
000005b0: 199c 3079 0117 8306 609e 0448 bca1 1030  ..0y....`..H...0
000005c0: b21a 5b0e fd29 77d1 070f 2810 02e6 5413  ..[..)w...(...T.
000005d0: d21f 6801 3f7c d6d2 fd05 ba73 df5d 2702  ..h.?|.....s.]'.
000005e0: 3fbe fc62 fd9d d033 eaad c5d9 9e89 017b  ?..b...3.......{
000005f0: 0ab4 091e cf49 f5e6 8a88 1493 98be 79dc  .....I........y.
00000600: 8f36 4b70 579b 86fe 95da 1ae0 8b08 9168  .6KpW..........h
00000610: 3601 29ee dd47 0e6e 736c d8ca b822 e279  6.)..G.nsl...".y
00000620: c35d 0319 7b3d a94e 19ee f0a1 7c33 19cb  .]..{=.N....|3..
00000630: cd54 8c39 77cc 3ac9 9eeb 56ab 6924 2f3f  .T.9w.:...V.i$/?
00000640: 63fd f95d ac91 30d0 42c3 2070 316e c3e8  c..]..0.B. p1n..
00000650: 3435 3e90 3216 6d2c a8f9 746d 60d1 485f  45>.2.m,..tm`.H_
00000660: d09c accb 5f74 7918 d7a1 70c7 d3dd 3f5d  ...._ty...p...?]
00000670: c495 bf6c 9801 9a39 22ab ab7b 2aca 1d70  ...l...9"..{*..p
00000680: 5e15 943a d4a1 3f67 94b1 f8fa 06f0 065f  ^..:..?g......._
00000690: 8a8a 9d33 61cc 4d40 8812 4e7f 956a 2973  ...3a.M@..N..j)s
000006a0: 42d5 87c7 ac20 5c3f f1e2 a76c ca21 15a0  B.... \?...l.!..
000006b0: 10a6 b5dd 7712 a097 9d1d 1e7d 0711 43a3  ....w......}..C.
000006c0: 6877 abf8 90b6 9ebb 1aa6 ef77 7885 de97  hw.........wx...
000006d0: 99ad 69dd 59bf 1f4b 4506 7dc7 ab63 ae84  ..i.Y..KE.}..c..
000006e0: 8179 bc16 9813 7944 ead2 5357 efaa 5fd2  .y....yD..SW.._.
000006f0: f390 7c19 d59e 64b0 d09a 38da 8bcf 44f5  ..|...d...8...D.
00000700: e18c 2728 a781 3171 d77b 409b 5a65 574e  ..'(..1q.{@.ZeWN
00000710: 1320 c0ff d8cd f84a 08b2 2cf4 3fdb 8bd5  . .....J..,.?...
00000720: ca16 19e2 33cf 1590 7382 777a 7182 ffd8  ....3...s.wzq...
00000730: 1c7b 2cff bba3 287a 9dc4 8788 4690 6bad  .{,...(z....F.k.
00000740: cda1 4aae 4c9d 8846 203c 001c 048e dff8  ..J.L..F <......
00000750: 8c0b ccda 0404 1b6b 19fc 7b10 ad0e 7980  .......k..{...y.
00000760: c9d8 aea6 3ba8 f71e 6321 174c 1d5e 9d30  ....;...c!.L.^.0
00000770: e2da e520 e621 57c5 051e 1eeb 9247 0e1a  ... .!W......G..
00000780: 9577 13ec d500 52b1 86b8 fea9 a1d3 14f6  .w....R.........
00000790: 3416 b971 00d5 3577 a4b6 1a6c a49f 7d9d  4..q..5w...l..}.
000007a0: aa3f c9b4 77be 468b 8b29 117a 69e7 532b  .?..w.F..).zi.S+
000007b0: e92e b1d3 e7c3 93f9 d466 f782 67cd e507  .........f..g...
000007c0: 1a86 2726 ceae 39d6 dbe8 a9e3 de82 7918  ..'&..9.......y.
000007d0: d693 d879 1fc4 2a9b 14b4 5a0b 8da2 fd5b  ...y..*...Z....[
000007e0: c423 b44f db27 013c e11b 9932 4498 9617  .#.O.'.<...2D...
000007f0: 2015 557b 6acb 8972 8016 982b 9a89 c2ce   .U{j..r...+....
00000800: 53a1 9beb 1a54 fffa 0bf9 dd76 7efa ef14  S....T.....v~...
00000810: 0e44 ab06 1956 36fd 8f79 e56f 1a10 e793  .D...V6..y.o....
00000820: cdb5 75ee 73aa 7ff6 a698 044e 73da 0360  ..u.s......Ns..`
00000830: 6a4f 3386 f958 6059 2098 3041 a124 4d0d  jO3..X`Y .0A.$M.
00000840: 1568 3eda 6864 5401 bdca 4ef8 e337 4d8a  .h>.hdT...N..7M.
00000850: b848 7844 89e1 919e 502b 13e8 8420 aee4  .HxD....P+... ..
00000860: a4c6 fda9 ef97 031b b293 05c1 54cf bbee  ............T...
00000870: 15d3 985b 3396 4e54 f103 a1f7 e394 bb2b  ...[3.NT.......+
00000880: 55a8 f97b 0351 aae2 93da b4c7 4013 087d  U..{.Q......@..}
00000890: 02d7 a4da 46ab 4ead c5b0 5bd2 4ad6 d417  ....F.N...[.J...
000008a0: 4b85 153e b9f3 78f1 b1ca e3a4 64e8 2a23  K..>..x.....d.*#
000008b0: 1b80 66e7 1e3d c1d6 738b 8795 910d a92a  ..f..=..s......*
000008c0: 41f6 68eb b935 41a5 8a8b f087 206e 9098  A.h..5A..... n..
000008d0: 93d5 9a9e 18d1 ec21 5885 be00 469a c369  .......!X...F..i
000008e0: a508 5236 8783 8770 6963 b811 0888 effa  ..R6...pic......
000008f0: 3150 a883 2d38 7a37 08c0 6da4 66c7 1330  1P..-8z7..m.f..0
00000900: 20ff 0d8d 265d f127 8ec0 8e7e e7a1 2e46   ...&].'...~...F
00000910: 1867 64ae a0fb 2309 08e4 b1d2 64b6 9ac3  .gd...#.....d...
00000920: eda2 1f50 6985 c08a 2a12 de5b d381 d5d2  ...Pi...*..[....
00000930: 3d5e cb3d 487b 5b12 65ad 511f 8c44 5d08  =^.=H{[.e.Q..D].
00000940: 264e 5380 c87c b8ff c6fb bb8e 5000 4d16  &NS..|......P.M.
00000950: 6d04 f197 4ed6 2b06 de4b ea0e 7f16 89de  m...N.+..K......
00000960: dbc6 efbe b74d 473b db7f 2d2d c649 0481  .....MG;..--.I..
00000970: 0f7b d4ff e394 0520 1599 13f8 1a07 687c  .{..... ......h|
00000980: 1eee 196b 8a30 2d8b 591a 6fed ddfd baa2  ...k.0-.Y.o.....
00000990: 84af 289a ba99 0291 0009 662f 5e65 4a41  ..(.......f/^eJA
000009a0: 8053 3aab c021 ba28 f714 d7d2 c733 bc0e  .S:..!.(.....3..
000009b0: b6c4 fd7a fca7 a9bc 54cd 0044 cbe2 3dee  ...z....T..D..=.
000009c0: b815 7dc2 04c3 0438 af02 cd02 0a2a ef31  ..}....8.....*.1
000009d0: bc1b d46e 3d31 af38 db31 0639 11d5 1488  ...n=1.8.1.9....
000009e0: 7178 8970 28e8 302a c9c3 6236 0216 64a1  qx.p(.0*..b6..d.
000009f0: 9ddd e02d 8365 198a f7bf c4e8 fba6 60dc  ...-.e........`.
00000a00: 885b 00c2 50fd 2d14 15f3 85ef c77c 4eb4  .[..P.-......|N.
00000a10: e0d3 b318 9a31 f92e a715 9403 749f 0d03  .....1......t...
00000a20: 86a1 969c 4d2f ee8e 1032 1c1d fc88 05b2  ....M/...2......
00000a30: 82de 4d7f d437 4cc4 518d cb98 4871 e063  ..M..7L.Q...Hq.c
00000a40: b5ed 38f3 b5b0 6a3b 2408 350a ee07 17c1  ..8...j;$.5.....
00000a50: c129 a6b4 ed10 da4c 2778 3f96 f29e afb9  .).....L'x?.....
00000a60: 86b2 685d 9882 70e6 f8c9 2683 b97c 96ea  ..h]..p...&..|..
00000a70: f965 3193 4778 75b8 f268 137b 9871 c0f7  .e1.Gxu..h.{.q..
00000a80: d5c2 e884 3923 26bb 57cc 40c4 5481 1307  ....9#&.W.@.T...
00000a90: 67d0 d400 2be8 b341 bf6a 7408 5b0d 76f4  g...+..A.jt.[.v.
00000aa0: 3a2d 1136 de24 f5a0 789d f080 5d3c 7dfb  :-.6.$..x...]<}.
00000ab0: 1570 f2bc b14f 3580 b52e bb68 1b63 26cc  .p...O5....h.c&.
00000ac0: c7a1 82d0 dbf4 8687 1aac 37b0 d6f2 54c3  ..........7...T.
00000ad0: 1712 d491 8f7a 57a2 2739 9070 2c09 043f  .....zW.'9.p,..?
00000ae0: d5ee 414f 9921 66e6 24a8 f703 e8e0 66c0  ..AO.!f.$.....f.
00000af0: fa60 d390 0cbf 898f 651c 21c8 a333 dad5  .`......e.!..3..
00000b00: 56db 499b fdfe 7b4c 28c7 fe97 277f 25f0  V.I...{L(...'.%.
00000b10: ad3f e83d 7765 365d d9c9 6c85 5749 7982  .?.=we6]..l.WIy.
00000b20: 4b4e d59b 7257 0313 7925 f86e 012f 7669  KN..rW..y%.n./vi
00000b30: f379 bfc8 309a 6742 15be 5519 b09e cdce  .y..0.gB..U.....
00000b40: 222f 9e76 d8c8 c3cf 3d9b 8d56 6a9a 9dfd  "/.v....=..Vj...
00000b50: 44c2 6b05 f6aa d8b6 f26a b726 ff01 de24  D.k......j.&...$
00000b60: 0fd7 cae9 8b0f cb4b 2b63 dbee 340e c597  .......K+c..4...
00000b70: b836 716d 3788 82fa 4dee d5cf f71e d6c2  .6qm7...M.......
00000b80: 1c07 f1bb cc3a 9be1 0fa3 9dee 1fc4 f75f  .....:........._
00000b90: 5398 b922 35b1 a9e9 813b 929c 8186 00a5  S.."5....;......
00000ba0: c20a fa1d 4585 7009 eef9 f141 0487 613f  ....E.p....A..a?
00000bb0: 12a9 c647 5d8e ecb9 9601 785f b449 43ce  ...G].....x_.IC.
00000bc0: c610 1bd5 aa9b 9886 174f f3f5 0971 63af  .........O...qc.
00000bd0: ee21 508c 6185 61f0 c239 abe0 2a00 a65d  .!P.a.a..9..*..]
00000be0: 8285 8892 13bc 64b0 35be 18e2 fd16 98fc  ......d.5.......
00000bf0: 8ddd 4269 9e24 e33e 9e55 481d 5f21 2d05  ..Bi.$.>.UH._!-.
00000c00: ddfc 241a fefd d861 8a23 5a5d 104a 3397  ..$....a.#Z].J3.
00000c10: 029d 076e 322e e2be f81b 2010 8cfe 5e35  ...n2..... ...^5
00000c20: 4133 92f0 5eab c5ae 6929 a20d 5617 6a1d  A3..^...i)..V.j.
00000c30: 0c85 5db8 aa26 41b1 e892 ba10 4b6c f1cb  ..]..&A.....Kl..
00000c40: 09b2 7906 e007 ec42 2664 82cd d0c5 987e  ..y....B&d.....~
00000c50: af76 160a 38af 3fe2 212f e4b0 302a e099  .v..8.?.!/..0*..
00000c60: 754d b9fc 83ed bec5 88b6 d45d ec76 efd9  uM.........].v..
00000c70: db13 2b75 9527 083c f26f 4208 5167 f48f  ..+u.'.<.oB.Qg..
00000c80: 61b7 bcf0 120f 7ba6 bd61 633b 5bf3 01fa  a.....{..ac;[...
00000c90: 74b2 7658 b0da 09a8 0d82 4997 6b60 f824  t.vX......I.k`.$
00000ca0: f95b 3651 2a6c eb46 f539 ec8f 436b b099  .[6Q*l.F.9..Ck..
00000cb0: 04a5 88ef 07a2 2be9 585d 1a74 2cf9 a282  ......+.X].t,...
00000cc0: ee69 1b53 5e3c db2d 4522 3007 b7a8 ac94  .i.S^<.-E"0.....
00000cd0: a213 7949 13c6 f09e 1c44 f1bd f731 d8ee  ..yI.....D...1..
00000ce0: 40c5 16a5 8509 a623 2a2f b86b 6e45 6f14  @......#*/.knEo.
00000cf0: eb45 759a b7e7 f695 352c dfde db75 4e15  .Eu.....5,...uN.
00000d00: 8f2e fc5b 0482 ca83 7983 07db bed3 de72  ...[....y......r
00000d10: c6d4 ee06 64e2 69ee 50e4 5bf2 d416 e2d2  ....d.i.P.[.....
00000d20: 6970 dc3e f080 6e60 dc3e ce5e e1f0 d13d  ip.>..n`.>.^...=
00000d30: b595 a3e3 6908 5d85 101b d60c 2a90 0e7b  ....i.].....*..{
00000d40: a510 0fe8 c1e9 74ef 5fec 86c6 91bf a6bd  ......t._.......
00000d50: 1cf9 8359 d3da d74f f724 6869 fe05 3db4  ...Y...O.$hi..=.
00000d60: 1539 0464 be96 ed2c 2ae0 1c1b 618e 1cf5  .9.d...,*...a...
00000d70: 8a0d 02d6 12e5 97f3 b27f 7f94 1ea6 96cb  ................
00000d80: 6760 6627 d7f4 3ff8 a141 0449 ec4d a84f  g`f'..?..A.I.M.O
00000d90: 95a8 b5f7 851a 652e 251a 5634 0854 d9d0  ......e.%.V4.T..
00000da0: 064e d42b 6719 c8a2 03c2 da32 c323 af4a  .N.+g......2.#.J
00000db0: c816 7f80 7148 fa7e 9c1b 69cb 0dd4 4789  ....qH.~..i...G.
00000dc0: b5ec d0c4 5ab0 eea2 3759 e2fe bafe 5736  ....Z...7Y....W6
00000dd0: e258 5c6b 6456 b01f 3f44 fbd3 9dbf d294  .X\kdV..?D......
00000de0: d412 5d38 bb79 e2f2 a38b 6af2 4201 4b48  ..]8.y....j.B.KH
00000df0: ef2b e4be 886d 3668 55cf f5b3 a467 83c5  .+...m6hU....g..
00000e00: 6709 e88f d985 5026 5d9a f7de 9e43 308b  g.....P&]....C0.
00000e10: 41a6 3018 0e07 10bf d3f2 4450 87f8 c329  A.0.......DP...)
00000e20: b258 3b17 af1b 01aa 4723 9b95 4b72 d4de  .X;.....G#..Kr..
00000e30: 8464 b9ab b1af 4caa 3bdb 5e2c dc27 4c69  .d....L.;.^,.'Li
00000e40: 9d05 c2d3 cfe7 057e 8048 a2b4 385b cd6e  .......~.H..8[.n
00000e50: 350a a703 5a28 0a6e 88b9 4cb0 b62a 1d12  5...Z(.n..L..*..
00000e60: 4149 2f24 0643 b321 5f1e e792 8cf4 7e97  AI/$.C.!_.....~.
00000e70: f22b b64e 5452 0780 675c b4c1 a7f6 85be  .+.NTR..g\......
00000e80: b1f6 1e3b ec21 dacb cab5 cbd0 8fea 8da4  ...;.!..........
00000e90: a277 5857 fedd d992 95fc 7618 1a3c 1e6b  .wXW......v..<.k
00000ea0: 8511 2b6a 9919 ea1d e278 fa7c b38f 94c0  ..+j.....x.|....
00000eb0: 21da 9b2c 11ae 772b 3873 e68b 6ee7 9adf  !..,..w+8s..n...
00000ec0: 0d48 e452 f009 3db8 d234 9d57 58d9 f0b8  .H.R..=..4.WX...
00000ed0: 60cd 7fb5 1e7c 5f56 2fde 0a84 55e3 c88c  `....|_V/...U...
00000ee0: 2d70 985e 146f d6cb a4e8 6751 6444 82a2  -p.^.o....gQdD..
00000ef0: e791 d5ea 33e6 9f51 7209 ee4a b4c3 9f2a  ....3..Qr..J...*
00000f00: 3e73 32d3 0c78 1a4f 3115 8188 a25e 64db  >s2..x.O1....^d.
00000f10: 9a45 3ade 5bb2 75e6 fa5a 1718 b1f2 80e6  .E:.[.u..Z......
00000f20: 722a ccea f225 be6e d483 78fb 5218 c841  r*...%.n..x.R..A
00000f30: 9e28 b0fd b787 c7cc f04b 5039 d612 1bd7  .(.......KP9....
00000f40: 6fa8 5447 f0f5 b62e ebf8 f098 41ec 27f0  o.TG........A.'.
00000f50: 92be db83 5c1b 52be 53d7 42bd 2268 0eb7  ....\.R.S.B."h..
00000f60: 02cd 2c8b 34a4 4d24 8f23 1840 96e5 abd4  ..,.4.M$.#.@....
00000f70: 92f5 8da2 92b3 3619 97f3 767c 2269 d7a9  ......6...v|"i..
00000f80: bb3f aadb 2ddd 3208 2aa1 41a2 fed6 d326  .?..-.2.*.A....&
00000f90: de71 f82c 4803 c531 5be1 275a 9c7d 6880  .q.,H..1[.'Z.}h.
00000fa0: 690f b052 84aa 0d00 3ef7 9b5c 5e5a eadf  i..R....>..\^Z..
00000fb0: 4991 2419 9bd4 2d99 a328 6064 65a5 f6d5  I.$...-..(`de...
00000fc0: 9d0f ab33 7dff 08e7 4a22 66b1 1197 a591  ...3}...J"f.....
00000fd0: 7936 470f ad58 1c1e 0bb7 43a5 15da daea  y6G..X....C.....
00000fe0: 0c68 f252 d625 d615 7725 0cf0 9c22 9e44  .h.R.%..w%...".D
00000ff0: bb0d 87b0 7e4d deb8 7015 aef4 0d4c b564  ....~M..p....L.d
00001000: f0d2 024b 40da ac56 b792 ca09 0976 39cf  ...K@..V.....v9.
00001010: 41ef 3992 abae 029a 7f4c 60f3 0b0c 9edf  A.9......L`.....
00001020: 5940 3460 36e5 87ad 7181 655d b8f3 f014  Y@4`6...q.e]....
00001030: 90fc 356b e547 a3d2 86e5 4502 3a6a 61a8  ..5k.G....E.:ja.
00001040: 2fc8 ee5a a54b 936a 9d44 77ff cd97 51b6  /..Z.K.j.Dw...Q.
00001050: 5cd2 c7c2 a832 1083 b778 8d41 76be f143  \....2...x.Av..C
00001060: 6b7c 9036 90c0 2079 ccb6 9a9a 58b6 36d3  k|.6.. y....X.6.
00001070: cb12 cb72 4469 72dd af7b bae2 25ba a139  ...rDir..{..%..9
00001080: f891 9a17 9fc3 ae79 4783 41c5 828b b816  .......yG.A.....
00001090: 64ca 032f 9e1d c279 ecad e5ed 14a9 a668  d../...y.......h
000010a0: 3cad d0e6 f3a2 9a82 972e d2e7 ac6b 4094  <............k@.
000010b0: 31bc c2e0 4339 1cfe 1224 da7b 1007 4386  1...C9...$.{..C.
000010c0: ff0e ab8b 67cf b597 b821 6133 2e4b 38ba  ....g....!a3.K8.
000010d0: c96b a7f3 ae2c cc62 6c40 5ed6 9f85 a844  .k...,.bl@^....D
000010e0: 9247 fc59 0251 ffa2 4302 64a9 2171 a1b2  .G.Y.Q..C.d.!q..
000010f0: b4f9 dad2 f916 44f3 7fc7 090b 4524 696f  ......D.....E$io
00001100: 9a59 9de0 3079 88c2 a8d7 562d 39a3 26e0  .Y..0y....V-9.&.
00001110: 2deb 5c6a 2c50 2f6d 7c9f 6d07 2e8d 0429  -.\j,P/m|.m....)
00001120: 0c6f 2ce9 b0d3 3398 3e43 2d80 4b99 ca05  .o,...3.>C-.K...
00001130: 034e 2827 c116 d5be 5ef7 2b65 2cce 6c2d  .N('....^.+e,.l-
00001140: bb8f 3b49 a389 ed1c 1b94 fc27 f6f8 36c4  ..;I.......'..6.
00001150: 302e 18f1 f584 5f23 4a59 a015 0d34 4a8f  0....._#JY...4J.
00001160: 9d7c 62b7 0fcc 9517 1a36 0bdc 78f2 3c3d  .|b......6..x.<=
00001170: ed91 cd17 e37b e74e 8f7f d9e8 1046 9277  .....{.N.....F.w
00001180: de99 3e43 8114 6554 5bb8 f7e4 4821 cb8b  ..>C..eT[...H!..
00001190: a56b 5263 310f 8c01 7704 e268 da74 f05f  .kRc1...w..h.t._
000011a0: 3c4c 0e04 7114 f3cd 9de3 c5f8 f532 8f9d  <L..q........2..
000011b0: cae7 361f 0ef4 c89c 5e26 8ba7 5c5f 1421  ..6.....^&..\_.!
000011c0: 4d18 6659 8f28 5dcd 171e cc84 f5dc 610b  M.fY.(].......a.
000011d0: 595f 8427 5702 eef4 863f 7d71 9eb2 8851  Y_.'W....?}q...Q
000011e0: 4700 5b05 9935 c7b1 57de 75d5 d4a7 2d56  G.[..5..W.u...-V
000011f0: 0bc6 6486 c6e4 1d73 d834 dcaf 6aeb ab44  ..d....s.4..j..D
00001200: 573c d196 bfb1 5fb1 cd20 7c1c e2d7 61a9  W<...._.. |...a.
00001210: 29cb 8fbc a0b4 f22a ecae cf6e a8c3 2795  )......*...n..'.
00001220: 9288 95a6 8b8a e7b6 8649 0387 a0d2 28da  .........I....(.
00001230: 002a 8dd2 16d1 a685 8fba 3d49 6b57 6743  .*........=IkWgC
00001240: 3ea3 252c 49ac a8d7 b991 55fd facc c0c9  >.%,I.....U.....
00001250: 417c 7e02 bd9d 320f 3e66 c879 b487 1574  A|~...2.>f.y...t
00001260: 17f3 ed1f d6b5 a1e4 e725 628f b933 5644  .........%b..3VD
00001270: e26b d0e1 14ed d598 f3a9 d210 9a0d eb24  .k.............$
00001280: 1f70 71c1 635d 0e23 01e1 e7b8 11cb cc41  .pq.c].#.......A
00001290: a8d9 a937 3246 5114 d881 415f 96f6 4554  ...72FQ...A_..ET
000012a0: 26e2 f6d7 b611 0f84 b92b b0c5 b3ee 3df0  &........+....=.
000012b0: b295 8cd9 211c 10f9 9020 0f1d 002b 600f  ....!.... ...+`.
000012c0: cbe8 0541 dbc4 2de5 6c87 f0b3 40b0 2fca  ...A..-.l...@./.
000012d0: acd2 8925 3ab2 8724 edf3 4a09 34a8 10b4  ...%:..$..J.4...
000012e0: ea9c b3ea 3aef b87c 8a5a 5289 3c94 44bb  ....:..|.ZR.<.D.
000012f0: 57f5 65a1 30f1 1b03 caf7 4fe0 91fc 23f6  W.e.0.....O...#.
00001300: 82a9 5545 c245 92b6 23a7 8f5f 1995 f955  ..UE.E..#.._...U
00001310: 3165 82be aeab a3a3 52ee 64ea 7d92 7178  1e......R.d.}.qx
00001320: 8988 b358 1a67 b483 c959 83a3 d9eb 2a1c  ...X.g...Y....*.
00001330: 99f3 3c1a e9d0 3974 7a30 ccf7 faca 3ca2  ..<...9tz0....<.
00001340: 01cc 5e18 b367 e962 7df0 6796 cae4 7a76  ..^..g.b}.g...zv
00001350: f005 3c80 1812 baea da78 8a88 9ff5 e081  ..<......x......
00001360: 5160 9cf8 8b8a d39d b766 7e8b a6ae 865e  Q`.......f~....^
00001370: aba3 6d01 4e10 c523 7370 3de3 304a 84e1  ..m.N..#sp=.0J..
00001380: 9bfb c6f6 15d7 08e5 bff9 6ab9 0dc2 6d6b  ..........j...mk
00001390: 6722 e527 c015 9176 c460 b124 7526 a33d  g".'...v.`.$u&.=
000013a0: 1511 d61d 9893 672c a8d3 071d 85d7 69f1  ......g,......i.
000013b0: c74e 8a4a 760f e7ff 736d c9b1 9d69 1916  .N.Jv...sm...i..
000013c0: becb 8aec 9c45 ae14 25a5 7992 8a5e dd80  .....E..%.y..^..
000013d0: 5359 91ee 6276 e058 6164 c9d1 2946 6a3f  SY..bv.Xad..)Fj?
000013e0: 852a 5eff 300d e344 e2de 3a94 bb8e dd19  .*^.0..D..:.....
000013f0: ecb2 0413 bbdf 84a3 7e19 88f4 7314 85ea  ........~...s...
00001400: 66d9 d10a 149b 554c 2001 1bbb 4aff af4e  f.....UL ...J..N
00001410: 73ce 1753 7803 6cb3 9a9b aeac 50b9 9522  s..Sx.l.....P.."
00001420: 58af 7fec c355 59a0 0487 db4e b418 9d77  X....UY....N...w
00001430: 2ca5 5d88 01f6 8f34 4906 fc9a 8fd0 c7fc  ,.]....4I.......
00001440: 088f b2db 26d2 7b89 d2b9 58e0 3e0d 5b69  ....&.{...X.>.[i
00001450: 65b8 548f f5bf 592d 7caa 3053 3d8e 1507  e.T...Y-|.0S=...
00001460: 23e3 3a4f 2652 9f8c 539b 24ab b4f8 0cc9  #.:O&R..S.$.....
00001470: 7677 59f3 74fe 617b 8db3 bec8 fd54 34c2  vwY.t.a{.....T4.
00001480: ca92 2c34 57a5 0741 c5a1 40f5 9be4 d8ef  ..,4W..A..@.....
00001490: f1ea 38d0 2bb4 abe2 0796 e96c dd22 eacd  ..8.+......l."..
000014a0: 30d2 7b6e b91c 3016 5059 1f8b 8f9b 4dd8  0.{n..0.PY....M.
000014b0: 56ce f3d2 a345 130b d9db dd9e b09b c0f7  V....E..........
000014c0: 6e44 f4f2 bd96 3976 e9e6 285c 46ad e24c  nD....9v..(\F..L
000014d0: 436a 5833 59a9 790f daf3 c618 c3c7 da76  CjX3Y.y........v
000014e0: 4e0a 16ba f981 5bab 9282 eeaf 44a9 e047  N.....[.....D..G
000014f0: f9de 9098 ecf1 6d2c 6dcf 8be4 bc67 2801  ......m,m....g(.
00001500: d582 336f 9c3c 9679 56c3 7de9 f536 b7b4  ..3o.<.yV.}..6..
00001510: a16e 3347 c6a9 27ff 26a9 ab7e 0746 8fc6  .n3G..'.&..~.F..
00001520: ef07 144c 461d 9f81 dfcb b724 3434 7121  ...LF......$44q!
00001530: 5da3 a2a2 ee40 c23e f0bc 261b 4d27 7f06  ]....@.>..&.M'..
00001540: 842d 6195 6ec4 4ac2 d7db 8758 de4a 3a2b  .-a.n.J....X.J:+
00001550: ddb4 4b91 94b3 aa36 2f6f b065 3a51 d27a  ..K....6/o.e:Q.z
00001560: 7350 e7ab bff6 b779 e89a 048c bfef 7ff0  sP.....y........
00001570: 95e9 c771 7415 e97d 5dfc 1947 243f 0818  ...qt..}]..G$?..
00001580: 4353 435e 50d4 f0e4 0754 5e3b 22b9 4030  CSC^P....T^;".@0
00001590: 28a4 0aca 2421 e3fa 625c 4a5c b62b 17c4  (...$!..b\J\.+..
000015a0: f7d8 f044 cc1f 3a6b 4be6 d8e4 83c6 09d3  ...D..:kK.......
000015b0: 78e6 6a1b 50b4 3220 0efb 739b 1200 0621  x.j.P.2 ..s....!
000015c0: 4d51 5ac0 7aa3 0544 5715 46b4 869a 4f6a  MQZ.z..DW.F...Oj
000015d0: b814 01f3 5280 57ed 0c7a 025f 68f6 ea96  ....R.W..z._h...
000015e0: a655 51b4 4fcf a63d 5385 6c95 f438 7d01  .UQ.O..=S.l..8}.
000015f0: d43a db0a 6e55 6f3a 6235 f2e6 813a 03f8  .:..nUo:b5...:..
00001600: a506 33ee 412c 94be d61b 5a56 151e 7405  ..3.A,....ZV..t.
00001610: 5f97 0055 8bac d6ba 5951 3a6f 56c2 6a46  _..U....YQ:oV.jF
00001620: a943 c889 bd12 82bb 9655 06ed 1cf7 7397  .C.......U....s.
00001630: a6c8 7778 458a 0808 ebf4 f0e9 74a0 49a8  ..wxE.......t.I.
00001640: 0431 0d5b 6d0b 370a cb1b 05f0 6e65 c90e  .1.[m.7.....ne..
00001650: cf65 8af6 a4b8 0f06 9517 de7b 3c37 6325  .e.........{<7c%
00001660: be4b bbb7 51f7 d670 7612 a5b5 29b4 da2f  .K..Q..pv...)../
00001670: fed7 1c95 269b 43aa 7814 4376 d183 72a0  ....&.C.x.Cv..r.
00001680: d815 40bb 8dbd 5425 3132 0273 a9eb 82f0  ..@...T%12.s....
00001690: 2db9 f045 aee1 963e dc2f 5ef1 7833 9a32  -..E...>./^.x3.2
000016a0: 2f7c c2b0 d20a 48e9 85e6 679d 84a3 2386  /|....H...g...#.
000016b0: cf44 9511 402f 95d8 28af 4861 4d60 e957  .D..@/..(.HaM`.W
000016c0: b96f 8be8 201c a3d8 124f ab95 7bb5 e237  .o.. ....O..{..7
000016d0: 725f 7b5e 72e5 5ed1 4189 cf1c bdbb a1e8  r_{^r.^.A.......
000016e0: 2626 117c cf18 2425 1831 51ea 09d4 3521  &&.|..$%.1Q...5!
000016f0: 9841 40af f399 ccd7 0d3f 7b54 7b0e 06ad  .A@......?{T{...
00001700: f8e4 0f59 764a 42c7 4edd f581 711c 400c  ...YvJB.N...q.@.
00001710: 24e5 93f9 1d89 3d40 84d1 0336 860a f868  $.....=@...6...h
00001720: 7055 e149 d8c8 2b6d 6b26 44e6 8a80 40f4  pU.I..+mk&D...@.
00001730: a41a c18a 5305 fb9c 08e4 69c8 2007 21ac  ....S.....i. .!.
00001740: 32c8 1deb 33a9 5ef9 037d e272 37eb ee7f  2...3.^..}.r7...
00001750: 6b02 77ed b59d c55f 4e4c b8ac 9a84 a064  k.w...._NL.....d
00001760: e63f 9421 54b2 8357 99c0 08e1 b6de 76e4  .?.!T..W......v.
00001770: 75d9 3a7f 093b b674 a0f4 4c67 4e13 104a  u.:..;.t..LgN..J
00001780: 6fd1 7916 76fb ee71 8d19 66c6 f2bf 0eb3  o.y.v..q..f.....
00001790: da5f 2d96 0d2f 5645 2ccd 3e53 5f46 6b11  ._-../VE,.>S_Fk.
000017a0: 0629 8576 bc0f 56f1 7230 f6a1 d53f cfe8  .).v..V.r0...?..
000017b0: 7c4b ca50 1ee3 707a 551f 5809 3526 b3a8  |K.P..pzU.X.5&..
000017c0: fb66 3b81 b710 7de1 5514 9b09 9878 65b1  .f;...}.U....xe.
000017d0: 27b4 8c4f 4e93 c1e7 d4be 4846 8ebf b855  '..ON.....HF...U
000017e0: 1cd0 9659 8d83 d273 bf98 7777 92af 1c8c  ...Y...s..ww....
000017f0: 6745 85e5 369a f9b3 1d93 8457 5f92 a87d  gE..6......W_..}
00001800: 4eeb be26 c0d2 899d 1b0a d11f 71aa cdaa  N..&........q...
00001810: d1e1 396c 2605 d809 befd 77f0 3ac2 15af  ..9l&.....w.:...
00001820: 1a86 c0b9 d70d b03e 5fa6 67cb 96df 1eb7  .......>_.g.....
00001830: dbee 739b d4d0 c3df e2cb c913 42cd 5b73  ..s.........B.[s
00001840: 0820 d8cd 0c0f 427e 5065 b3e9 dac5 2c23  . ....B~Pe....,#
00001850: 10c3 f632 1165 01e9 da04 28e7 1830 caee  ...2.e....(..0..
00001860: cb36 4ec2 7852 201f f9cf 3f37 9900 3a6d  .6N.xR ...?7..:m
00001870: 9481 7850 553b 6dbc ede6 2a12 e1e8 2b6d  ..xPU;m...*...+m
00001880: a2a9 5407 0e12 1132 fb7a 5ecc 7217 37b8  ..T....2.z^.r.7.
00001890: 1105 cefe fe01 9bc7 bf55 b7a2 0a7b 5f91  .........U...{_.
000018a0: b0d4 c6c0 98fd 0983 2e4c 09d4 2b5e 783f  .........L..+^x?
000018b0: bb80 a0b8 ca37 c067 87f1 e56b 03b5 c83a  .....7.g...k...:
000018c0: f155 2fcb 899a 99ce 11b9 b74f 8fd8 c924  .U/........O...$
000018d0: ad87 0ca7 7311 6b90 7d90 4fd0 86de 3242  ....s.k.}.O...2B
000018e0: f934 ab9a fce2 3a12 c8ad b862 18c1 4736  .4....:....b..G6
000018f0: 7b97 a1af 6dd3 a102 6616 c46c c411 f6a9  {...m...f..l....
00001900: 6481 0017 1c38 15d4 27c4 9511 13b2 d38e  d....8..'.......
00001910: bf6f 68ff aa2e 8a37 0bfa bf3f 6404 ae32  .oh....7...?d..2
00001920: c211 3d11 ffbb 2ab2 f3cf 9640 c3b4 ec26  ..=...*....@...&
00001930: 7c9e 39ff 2f19 3162 7a30 8c03 1039 52bb  |.9./.1bz0...9R.
00001940: f758 cf31 77f9 402d e631 4305 e259 ea91  .X.1w.@-.1C..Y..
00001950: f903 eb3d e0e1 41fa 1e0a 10a6 c00b 375f  ...=..A.......7_
00001960: 7290 d4d2 5eca f1f2 e6f1 9be9 39c0 8382  r...^.......9...
00001970: c37a 3d92 6c20 333d 3a66 7b80 c965 f72f  .z=.l 3=:f{..e./
00001980: 4cc6 613a 31e5 28dc 2b60 2e5a 29bb 4249  L.a:1.(.+`.Z).BI
00001990: 288d 1190 d7f9 a064 f598 e3b5 4017 b94b  (......d....@..K
000019a0: 7f02 0e11 09ad f758 7d70 6283 cc57 1420  .......X}pb..W. 
000019b0: 443b ec72 18fe 7fce 1cef 5fcc d6a7 f751  D;.r......_....Q
000019c0: 8586 80ce 83f9 ece5 e8aa 062f be38 79b3  .........../.8y.
000019d0: 0f4a 98fe 083c 60fc f20e f819 c488 565b  .J...<`.......V[
000019e0: 7aab 29c1 619e 8720 1078 b002 dcd1 2a46  z.).a.. .x....*F
000019f0: 950e b15a faf9 a195 a976 82d8 bb4b 38df  ...Z.....v...K8.
00001a00: e29c bbff 1029 60fc 2b09 ab8a 7c4b 92df  .....)`.+...|K..
00001a10: f151 9371 fb97 d64c 28d4 025d 337d 98d4  .Q.q...L(..]3}..
00001a20: 13e3 dfc9 a442 d740 7adf 31c6 4bb7 8779  .....B.@z.1.K..y
00001a30: b558 49a9 6975 2860 0ce6 15b1 63de f3d3  .XI.iu(`....c...
00001a40: 1f3e b142 a68c 796b d490 8eed 7d19 a576  .>.B..yk....}..v
00001a50: 5901 38d4 6261 4674 06f4 e153 d9d2 9fa7  Y.8.baFt...S....
00001a60: dd5f 196c e897 b843 aa7e d687 fc2f 48c3  ._.l...C.~.../H.
00001a70: e62a 9624 143d ba92 dddd e20c 2a24 f84c  .*.$.=......*$.L
00001a80: b7de d83d ecdb 2e64 0d3a bd55 bbd4 70ea  ...=...d.:.U..p.
00001a90: dedf 4ce7 deed 7bd3 7ff0 77f1 271a f586  ..L...{...w.'...
00001aa0: ed9c 01de 4704 af77 e59a 5cc6 0b8b 2dcb  ....G..w..\...-.
00001ab0: 2361 7401 6bca 5d5f 514a 842c dbf8 a04b  #at.k.]_QJ.,...K
00001ac0: 52c1 eaa6 8dcc 53a1 cf4c d423 4c52 f8a5  R.....S..L.#LR..
00001ad0: 1a36 d859 9b10 9689 dcbd b304 502a c279  .6.Y........P*.y
00001ae0: d32b a849 9433 c345 a982 65e0 46d3 4bf1  .+.I.3.E..e.F.K.
00001af0: 0275 808b 6000 4859 d8ca 5eeb 0917 b21c  .u..`.HY..^.....
00001b00: 8e76 b2fd 7b90 9702 aa71 ee4f 384d 012b  .v..{....q.O8M.+
00001b10: 6cea 0f6a 5d90 b451 88a2 953a e90f 61dd  l..j]..Q...:..a.
00001b20: 6cdc e29b 5d7c 1d69 bafc f0ae 07a0 b4f7  l...]|.i........
00001b30: a819 aedc 3602 170a 2235 a55c c943 07c2  ....6..."5.\.C..
00001b40: d3af a1e8 4c40 42be 8edf e1e7 0903 51a0  ....L@B.......Q.
00001b50: dc65 278c 1e69 8be5 8d0e fffb 47e7 b1e7  .e'..i......G...
00001b60: 2637 41ae bddc 6169 3257 a9bc d752 37bb  &7A...ai2W...R7.
00001b70: 77b9 59cb 3242 74ac 06e7 d284 a605 f812  w.Y.2Bt.........
00001b80: 701c 3b8c c955 2c60 7b45 1622 7ff2 976d  p.;..U,`{E."...m
00001b90: de41 bc17 d9ac 6423 b8c9 390c 5ac2 7855  .A....d#..9.Z.xU
00001ba0: f3fd 712a feb0 9fb2 e1ec c97c e094 f48e  ..q*.......|....
00001bb0: e5fc 6cf9 c5e3 c693 3f7c c5ad 746f f725  ..l.....?|..to.%
00001bc0: d7cd 91a8 0275 f351 0d6f 2df2 569b d5d1  .....u.Q.o-.V...
00001bd0: 7d1a a306 07e1 1677 a07e 3825 9ad3 f394  }......w.~8%....
00001be0: 879a 62ae 5604 fa92 dee7 7935 335b f7ff  ..b.V.....y53[..
00001bf0: b1b1 2523 9eba 7bdd 71dc 3644 400c a87b  ..%#..{.q.6D@..{
00001c00: 3be5 0612 bc82 e857 38ed d5f1 bb8a 31b7  ;......W8.....1.
00001c10: 111e 2085 4a1e fbf9 4eb1 3933 3345 4349  .. .J...N.933ECI
00001c20: 81c3 b793 ca52 1b25 b21f 21dd af59 04bc  .....R.%..!..Y..
00001c30: 53b7 e489 a4fa 071a 25e7 ef90 df8e 0306  S.......%.......
00001c40: 16a9 d5dc d548 313c a659 48bf c71f 47eb  .....H1<.YH...G.
00001c50: 47c0 8ecf 1ded 39db 6c45 a9a1 9c95 d436  G.....9.lE.....6
00001c60: c13a 34b4 4d31 7531 2bcc 17e2 5b0d 5257  .:4.M1u1+...[.RW
00001c70: bc85 dd3e 3a1e 4c48 38ca ce79 06bb a778  ...>:.LH8..y...x
00001c80: fc21 c861 d6e6 3f20 fe17 fbe5 0eb0 3c8d  .!.a..? ......<.
00001c90: cf83 44db 9468 354a 0e94 c734 89ab 9ef1  ..D..h5J...4....
00001ca0: 2f1a 2c00 1684 2dbe 3989 ad48 7e49 1abe  /.,...-.9..H~I..
00001cb0: 135c ab2a ddfd 77ec 5d75 cc54 fe00 31    .\.*..w.]u.T..1
```

Comment: This is very nice!

Comment: Very interesting! I’m not familiar with flif, but it appears to be vaguely similar to Huffman coding applied to groups of characters, which I thought would be a promising approach.

Comment: Take a look at the answer by nununoisy, which should have been a comment on yours but the poster didn't have the rep required for commenting. That answer shortens your bash script by using a pipe instead of an intermediate file. https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/205923/59825

Comment: I think you can also save 3 more bytes by using `sed 1,3d` instead of `tr -cd ACUG`.

Comment: What command did you use to produce your flif file? When I execute `flif --effort=100 -N imagefile.pgm compressedfile.flif`, I get almost the same as your output, but instead of the last 2 bytes, I'm getting 6 different bytes (so it's 4 bytes longer).  I'm curious what I'm doing differently from you.  (I downloaded the source code for flif to my Mac and compiled it.)

Comment: @MitchellSpector I also enabled some kind of a no checksum flag; it might be that. I believe nununoisy should keep their answer, because commenting on Stack Exchange is an extremely important privilege.

Comment: That's it -- thank you!  I added in the `-c` option to flif to prevent a CRC from being added, and I'm getting exactly the same file as you now.

Comment: A [suggested edit](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/60610) from [NoLongerBreathedIn](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78445/nolongerbreathedin) points out that you can do `<.pgm tr -cd ACUG` instead of `cat .pgm|tr -cd ACUG`. I've rejected this edit as per our policy on golfing other people's code in suggested edits (@NoLongerBreathedIn, you should leave comments to suggest golfs; you have more than enough reputation to do so), but I am leaving this comment here for your consideration.

Comment: FLIF file can be compressed losslessly down to 7280b - https://pastebin.com/raw/rB3H7Fvj

Comment: @hyper-neutrino I think when I made that suggested edit I didn't have enough rep to comment.

Answer (score 17):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/) -rzlib, <sup><s>85</s> <s>82</s> <s>80</s></sup> 77 + 1 + <sup><s>7309</s></sup> 7308 = <sup><s>7395</s> <s>7392</s></sup> 7386 bytes

```ruby
Zlib.inflate(IO.read'f').bytes{|i|$><<('%8b'%i).gsub(/../){$&.oct}};$><<?1*31
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##db1ruxW1Ei38ff@KljuoodOddBJBQAQEEUQFLyBCrggiolzk6k8/@x2jOj3Xcr/nrOfZa6Mya6aTStWoqlHVf71Ir/97/9WrMnz816AePnn64rl6/vCP4czQ7v/n/pkj0/B3xh//e/vxw4T/3B7H5/XYla/VXzWWo@3ocZVeP6/P3r57@O7QmdOnjx097NPRww@PqwfPXqRjJ5U6efztoSPqj/z8/ftT/Btn9YlZ//e/Y//5ZHA@5EHb4oaWzDyUybshT/M4tLGWwZSahjnnNgyvFH4@x/9Gpa6p0@o/qwQNGTkUM4whTENzZR6mir@fQs1DzLkM1U4F35D9MKj9Px@rTcYEGWNI0xAW74ds8PftNOkhuop/zN5gCT4OPo6bjI@//YD/d1rtZMyQobNpQ4j4dlOnMMxB44HclAeb53moCSuajbOQ8bVS148HpT76eVbKvOgyDGWU2oZpSiMWg2@fRNCUzWDSFIfqwziUMck6DnAJxyd19YTaW4flfthxHEadwuByadiUVoYxzXWY8cdh9tUNDkLWZ3nHX2fOKq/ebzIWyJjaNA/aNT1MI76zubRAWjLDEheso@Kpcg16GE4eVGoQOY8eqY9263CQsbSC79TLsn4cJxqGRUdsj501ntSnIacch@EPpRuXEdVFve9ZPGS0hoedZq2HUvCn1GIdSsKvtBj8u9bqUIuTZzm4nexn@N/bLiNwP1KxEBTiMBeco4nUlNosHrIuw9g8vyFP6358qr7Eb6gu5HUZETJssm7w2bghmjjiHx01Jbkh@ckP1kH41Bpk3PlBfaHUHarrsR8gp8tIkJHcDOV2PIMKPU3J4nAyDqdW/IoaKwpTXLAOhyNR6t72QF1Ghgzj8HW4JGEYHZRqDLoMuUCa5sa2MLahzs4MwxfHjr1W807bn3cZRWT4GXptl6GEEIbQahxczZl3KAyt@GWIJWAdeJDv@eF//r2OSj01WK1t2Q6pQKWLmyOeBdct@qoHuwQ/VG3lXPAYL9Qn/DyE3ekyGs@leRyh1w6aYi2WxSOpM@5ywy7g5KFyxi3rufxxC6sx8igv/9OvPp@FFwp6jU86gw/lCOVu1mA/FgedKeMQm6nDcOHF2RdHL@HjN9UD/L7eZdB@tBl3LlQHgzFNUIgZT@ANZCx5moYYHe7c5Fb9eKeOUMbjA@qp@qvLoP1Y8FGc6FIHP@GA2wLlTgna1lyY8SwZZ2VKGIZHB9ST/Waoy6D9mBac3uixa2PLIy6709AxnEsK2A@nxxm3KZVhwBLu4KN/KvmlNxm0H2NdZlxU3O5k8Ku6iWZtwrJijAM0rsF@ZNqgLDf/wP@sg/ZDL1CI5GGDqvYN97zg5kSToJ0Jchf8o59L2bOnn1z9lwzaD2vKhMXAQlQz4rbqQiugw5A1Hq14SJs8znu4uX8zrh7bZNB@2JE2K9iAFTVcshG3b1raOHiLs3IW@1wcFjjcOBN@UurGF9iXdy/21iH2Y3bz4NtkoRXUThjIwcDCDW7m82XDU4aZGtQzdRgfvXHu/jOlLjzeZIj9MBFfF8ZpmB1MDYzZDKWCAYBpmwY/Rtqx1Lgfr5V7CymvVNq3H7QfYYZ3a3PExQvVDr6MuHgVJixnWHg3Bjg7azJkfL6zYsefqotfdRm0H27S2PkGR2WgB8PiIW12ocKmjHlYCq7KYmGYh7/EVf5KM6J@f1k/6jJoP5yLFg4Wnsy7agZYQTolneFfsAsNd3AIGpdg@Htdxc9GyeEe6TJoP1yEfgRjPLUNBxwCVCPCcfuG05gcVBSXGvrxRqnLMOryc1Sp910G7UddcoCVgWIGmJ6hzCNvPHZSZ3iEccIqU9p81P/lvtB@lAofFYwe8dhFD6PVFTuDdYzc7EnD9y2VtpCuoa7w4fMP1JNuCyfajxZx3eo4435BUQdd8aEyB5j5eUrwL/CV0Vv4KNy45Z9zsoQP8b/bXQbtx8KtiLXhbkw0zGaChkccsCv4OE7VDE0DogzlsqKK4Jneq5u7Z5loP2A1gDoK1BHbAa0ICwy5lXsYyxACkEUy2WEd7@9egD3@Q1by9U4G7cdcYPwWi/vlEv6qqQAQDghiMKHB3TQ8RqULHz7FbrxV19Vf6gqeZCfDiN/HfuD28bLj22Oga7G4vGGGp3EabnIxkX7/zt6Z/KnKJoP2Y7b4ptQCljwG@mwggBhh23zM1BQswWQggMHelo@3VcpXusug/ZgBvnBb4WDjZDWwAyzPEjIOuEJZoWdwohmHPnxC5/SNUg/xPGqHCyfaj0rsYBK8ss7Y3XGGetkJmxIL5Fo4y2HKE/WDOv5eqW8VvdVHh7oM2o/FwdTUBYIisWWb24J9BoCYNQxLyAV@LhCPPXi3PsWnSj/b09OJ9sM04oSlULkb0C7v19I0rkoFlsrJAsPwEgxfryKO4HAfqV92MuL6LMtQJzgl66DSqY4aGwC/VXTS3A@YggInw/ty84fnKzblaroM2o/ZpEjbaYYw8kQDzInG/sDGwrK67OHHidEGuNnn61LCF@/2nkXwBxFlSlB4MycghqwBA@gqbIM50QFuwXncvuEr3H2ash8Fxrz6vMug/YA5hhbNUAjsHM0gIE2YEAe4BJGAeAJSiXEPZC7iGOAc/s9v66D9KA5/vxZLMwFNgRWFb5gWKHyYITIRQI@Llf24BQBz9MCvrwG4Ve0yaD/Cgk30CffLVGxA9nA3MPgAdhpGNTn4W@hMXm3Q9S8IyfbboJn2I414AmsdL@qMx8iAppa3D/@oBzPBQeQWxFfeeoNHoOPW59NOBu3HnGG@vYUNAvJoAJhQzDrCHOcKWzjNTtDrOAw402VbxMEXOxmTYAeAiykssBUJzm4ZoS6IGxY8GpBLhKHCKTtH7HD8d3X4vprU9b/UB@HvLoP2AzCywmzCfCdGC1FbMQCaTsNhbQ2XRgvWPvMBASpu79/4v2861p5pP6Jb4A0Z9LQRgVMmcgfOw4oMYAPiExyTg30c1G@MFvhTlPrh6NBl0H6YNMNWNC5eWw9NAToGukvQjxnbGRvtARY4XD0LN/ljVkevvp0YxXQZi8QN8M/F4/L6CIPhDDH/QtUIUP15htwpytm@YggEdYd2zD@e2PaU9iNo4tMZhzONMCLAyViMxUGMDMPSBO0xLaw6JjFQ7Ua5y6D9CAYmb6x2xlMRZmsGknOgosEMBt79abQrlvru6grplPpluNtl0H7oxKsFGMGt09gP3BdtccpQePjPCS7cmKnHpkc/yMfU4QNP1M8XjnUZtB8wiLC6ywjXHBFTTxU4yOUspiOuz2Id8elRRZCsbqzm7IftWWg/4Adw2Scc8DRFw2eBh9SO/w5X1nrYacsVYR3f/naAz/LiW/XjN98@6TJoP5aR0VYbaToIDlsFXMW/hCWGpiwam2IjgrrhvsRgSr2EmkSoWpdRVkzn8NgakBBOCnAOUKLA3UOBcd6ayGJ9Fqin@kmd62Hu7lloPyYDC7FohG0AER4KEYEyI7xK84BRYYSfqwzAh0MEMH5el7J392k/APIR2y9wmLBWsCQFtxV3Bm6hGUTtEbsLoyk2@fvNW175ZCfDiP3IgAieGjBGYAfPp6oVkUxgGOE8rEAY7Xq2d4EdFI8HweWPXQbtx4TDhXHHOSLmsVgCIn@7AH@0RUNQhZpPjEKGA08NY7E1qAMi6zJoP/KIrQsakdIywnotC10LrDViXjwBlB7K6gXzv1PX73eX/dPes8zr3QfmoSerhigCdxDGjFZAw2umBcuKfubdf/j3GsGsP2OXQfsREsIUOxPu14WhLSOZkqkVuPuMPQmtxCZ/p375nR@/Pe2di5H4JQFX@4APJepCAvKl309M6DiEiNCxlDPjys/WBXz7L7tuJP@RoeHAPAH7Aa2oQMaIyqBjzeJZ4PdhkxMCioFG7L5izP8vGU7yMHC1k8dijNEE3ECUC3wLYg8AGT1rPpWjfjw/9tkF4MrHitDh9rMuw697WgDy6VASMGArsDcWqBauBToz2YXRDS7eoH53gge/V@fvHs7qmy6D9mOiewfghm8o8FbaAXWkDNBSI/C6tZqIb4YdO74@xSMlTlPZLoP2A6eDuCF4RE9MNOhqEapa5ul4CRBs59VbDeqiJGDuMU@nHu/2g/ZjmqPcc5iOCIeJSwOj6mBEoPTwOaNdsCkRcfZB3Pk3b7iKD0RZuwzaD11NxD1neGDhqGZ6iRThIIJJtAcBMY1NtMlM46iz/6untB@ZAKUZbCwWD6zhGM4wU@CMYDS4FgvjLbEYNIxRFPzDme82GbQfo8XXNaKUJSBaqBrXLc0A@XpcoF6JEUQbx9UmP9w5ut06muB1fF31iOcmHqvJ2B4YEvi5peHSeFxZz2MCXme68qvNBHUZlvYD0Se3MxB2Ac4VxAzYGdy5NMIClgzkWf2Kg97QbvzS1bTjILvmTxmNTzO/WBPEBWZjcQWThWHJbcY@L5E4@eqBU@sK1FP16bKtg/bDFhiHUCuhCoxOpP0tBVu8MI4aA251hvoMw93tovyeP9z3LLQf44LTW7A5w0j85gpuTsy1IGqBtk38lccgcTZunHrP23vvo3s7GRK/pBmudnJMA0NPXbAMFOB@tYcl0dznReMbhg/n87hsr@@d/m7NPHYZdo1veb/gUf0MpJotbg5cNsBQgw0yOjCcyRLfnj/GDAqgw/TZ3rPQfoRMr6IrAwUcsF8mghZc2VyBcSMhb7Vy971Wmop@V5Buv/vWiV2He2oNp6d5ysDfcEozNjFGPAZsP4K6mXH2AYEeH2072@NsS/vhgAyYQQdAr9hJb2iS0oTrNiF0MSOvMb3x8Pz8aSrH8w8/Vurc3p7SflimwVIDeFoC7ujC@AWuAn4r4Qmi1titgrs8/HxAhYffxyOwhs@Ype8y4hp7WLhaGJHJwxxHOAKA/BmQ0DG54vBx7/BfGXtcPEa0/wnRpbrYZdB@tIIlA/PQoZQ8IIBYhsZ8YQH8B9qF3o2rnqoDRQoFEDbtnQvtR@Ylc4h6hoSLzp1hNAmgCxs7EUoUbLYTPPbnVYmibjsiiG1PJX6ZsQuZmZYSgWZgwQDaF5gk53HjPbM6tnrawu95KK8kIaQ@@2Vbh@Q/mmFibnRDCcD8hkn5zCyQDcAfE@HcuGjq@nkeKRMHP708dGz3LLQf0WIXIpGw9m3kOvAEHjYF3obBFILFXPWatzzDNVyGZX57c5Ox0H7AcuOizibTEgNg4jgAm6FousIUNDriJTvij4c0QMObVcUev@oyJH8aib0qELZtCKYmxipwlZGBIUxpHqEzNXRbeE9w3Y/qZ/VkWwftRwlAP5PBBsA/AwfNnuBprFBgHNiYDZNeE/fj9aEtpa3U@c9Pdhm0H8EBe@GmMC5nhJ6gXrUhMHQTVD9nw4u35umYCjr1iTr6l@JTdRm0H8Zi6wq/bubXhbwAlYpVJD61FopTTUIMBDd3fj6pIpHQras7GRK/FNhfPwMJxwzlNnrCVpgxQhA8JFQDeCJjn4drirngz07cBJ7C3XvTZYj9GAHATOR3GvwaK065WDiZsgDntQl3f5kmOdsvmUvqYWE60GUI/vCQkZnwyAl/vwFmDnAS8EwZxhoASQOjTfb/l2M73GV4wfxM8wUE295rZpIAOKqnTbbwNHPFVgQfqOuXBd4yYP/lzO7OLYI/DGyFnIZn3BV4wEvNzO8AvmsHezojwgDW/gJn8qPqCfLxVJdB@5E8gIHUCbX3ksxasBWTAcwG1Jzoau245nLUWmo49Mmdk@pGz@UstB9mnjNrOLBZM/GYZ9DDglKmyLpEGnyo4fD56TUL2wswr7sMyZ@O0I@4aLgRgC@oPuPKiTFhidiKDINoLWt8T3ka3/fVPLvVa3xLkboYFGJJtMkFRtXXWmHmvYTMEJ4YgM9Q/eGPE7@pu@F/c59LFVzYmMyCJS4WXzzDJQCvE48Vy0IE/oNp1DGg2yOK5ZcRMPfI15uOrfYDkWOqQeJbLJ4JZMM0Dnw2EEDEshbm/gdcVsa3L79W@aja3Vs3rvEt7tyS7RAL8KmkmPTMPMyCLcbZ0qOb2M/laxjkX4kg7n/ZZdB@JGuBLWfE5dHgcJaE08AuMNHGfCifKmRPvH6LN/c35rUu/DVu@@EEf@Dm4crCt1qLq5JhFgeA8MhqqdQsLKQxnvv@xqxundkA@5Yfc7OcCzYxWOhTmOFG5mVeCJs1rCiOulr4FzyQZ72S0cuyqB5KdRliPwKcknFRI7p2rAs0WMWaiDpYaou81ayFDFewgndvCciiJPu7DNqP1ArNT6B7MoxN4RdLwlkFFnYhltVgyWurWZ2@PF/k@Sh1tee1He2HrwkbUICWTMD9Whyckq6BJT@PO9csrmAZJVa/pq6oB2sk9NPv2zrcug7sAg1inempM5NZGoiS@YAhBTyVaA9kWKoYax6n9u2HFxvkiI5xXwLRT6zeUlk1E2dwtVLUnmazxurEQFIoPKFMlxEEw2Dn61xwtYgLlwAZCGlG5uhx6IhyYV0gaGDS8g7R9lM1nI2nTnQZUXJbDebKISINEcjMRAOlCkzGVBxY1qwAsko/CN73X57rV27uMpJgbc9bAh9VS2Ks0hBmjkxDzNiFxuRl9BvmX3@@23dvHe0HLHokqodqTHQtDQeM0APSJmjWVDLQXVu2@xL/uNypCo@6DIlfattSA467ECBjAQaCICOLgQYuEt8SdzxVlxHEXP5OXdrWIflTXQk9cKvmxBQMU9pAZlQ0uPBWcKGb3uovp9R7JmH3Pwvth@YRAhbCtwZGdg7ITLOQDvgBGMAE14x1bftxVOKf42qLG7zgj0VKznAoukLrq4eTpuqwSJ2A7qDmtk5xt6dfqVe4uc9/6Wfrpf4SmBDjkmOC54WaA47AX@OsIn0wttMSRQ8Pj@3zco/u9RjI035U42AL47LQreKWIBTkAzHjjyUUejw7S/3lnWrpiLp2NBOAbDGhl/rLPAp8wbGyIt88Lgi2gpFg0EDdnveWPBRmk37vy/hQXd1k0H7MhEypNsEO81AM2RYGvnKZC9UFOjOyUjd4tcXqWf0Rt3Pxkv8IdJNMhgOgw0d5AUP405gCQwDY5NlP67n8ypByDep8rxN6yX/wasG/Yic9ziXjX8OyUscyLrR2uDkzIdtwcEjXer4ANzh0X@lpP8ZIlbYskdCitamSQwIZCMAAo3Lln5LYoMOqJ@mu7umYl/glIh6GnrnVrkcmpkMDqtJQz8FbIE/joLYCTGHXOw76YpMh9dsqYcdE84M/uUz9IAqLHvZgJpDRSRPjXjz2sbq4Zj7trv7iaT@cBf6wAOzQSVZAAvQ6GDxGzqQHRPiLYmBYhhfqp/trLVsRAvgug/YD4TF2jVvhWMrDEgxMGBQ@0zTOeWGNe6aOqbNrAeYrdff0rzdclyH1l5EZiwnrqI7xnMeHxgkq6iy@fWRp2lsY6@Gcmu7L@T5/QVX5pMug/aiRmdeKT6ZErkfAniYo@@CqpHUhCHdm7vpBbPnyH/Wn3@2H4I@KT44ZIXZYSLdKsIChsOYvNeCR6M6n/8GWw97Z0n4kVhNrAnocyTgAbID3HmnhR@JkqZ0gOtjJeHwDcf@3SaX/dGoP7VhmXYxeaHGsG1nHzOvCIi6QizEs5GjfceEDZV9/Aud9YbeOsOIPh/sFcz5oQxhFO2Yt6ynM/6XFwHHPkrf8JzKhVG6xoHxly1sGqd8Wpn0cQgZoKIwZQDHwKc62VqEtIaRMxVFG6YltpnPeq6ddhuCPCtO74PpBqeB5G3ODI2vAOUYmhIHcJyrf8ET9yrN99m9cGCT/MTdYHgcE6qPQJbD4NjJtwQIRCyywyYB4w0Fmgr84ckVNl6Dsm00OtB@TZ9E3T5ou37JoiXDGw3DNobIMDVwzk503HGPeQooeAKlvx03GInoayGbCASdW2abEKG4BOLQAiwgoYCltzYl6upXUbzwmGuoyBH@YuTAxPcFr1sSUJUy6wzoM6w2IypjUyMx9fqr@WnfivERSXYYXXh@CJMcKNAIfeqbI7MGS8CfctEjH40ujjAP4KKX8Jgm/TYbUbzPAguUvRPkE6BOJEwyZmaLT5FFoJr2Gr879zMc5JGe7J0PqLzk42FOYzTrCAk4WhogZK1b2EKsj7sbjMvf5kcCowxeZdPhrT4bwxzxxsoGgnGE2xwaADr1zBPIQLv@hpbnj5FXhfyh7Mmg/qmVCPUCvsQ6SEuF@jRPTiPDOz7zQc9m7c@qLj//1LFJ/YerZCv2mQtuyVKBrG8lgwRUkpBl1Yw7l7raQi1@fvbyTQfth6OeA6WB6ycSLFrFpWkLC7sIemEp3Mzb4qMv77Md1dWOTIfwPsnci0xbBIaCdqeaIR9rQDHZmSgh/WpI60AWJJ6VO8OGbbR1R6i9TY2Ye3wmIh9sXcc8La2UT4irW1gxZbr229lY9QtTx8W11894mQ0t9nyrdWLjwgPuSAB3pITPzUs7XwMol7v7Xj5n5WH9e4cJ0GbQfc8JNmyIAh62wJN5JJAiThEfFQ7K6NTYc9XCqnsi/lF1q@0GXIfmPNnEdmbqOUKclYFHHyAfgDhA5strtF@pHTxXC7X8AvJ27DIlf5oW7RvLsiD2NITE3TrkZxkmzXIfAFev4/FF/kI/260eU@IURSiE3cF7gaicWPltjStbDJucaES2PpvuGhXf/mQCznuuLi@SCaYMQt0EXiB0KEykhMnNiyN0gw3WtNwBKkflxBap6b28dTjg1ZLqy1GCDZhIVVrGSPuIngD3jPaziVCQf9ObNT1IZU@8uw4Z0GX49F003WckFsnT@dXAsx0SiCEveUc3kOZ7qPKe/VyzUeY6R9gOGGB8v0Mk5eTIDSPkE7EZEmiam6BxTXdSxf3oApT7dv6dx5fYkJoWAm@xCpWLkA9iB24rgYaRhHhsUWGoFKr1a/39PhvA/WEhME5y/YY0PyINMPFjzwmcxBUYBGoR1jFDSc0yevmV0uJNB@zFq8ngYfY6kVDczQRBzBskXyReOLGasnE1CmKNnO9m6y5D4xXoELKQEJwNwWCamZcaZ9ZRsmCQjW7EI/niw0qz9ShLqMmg/LPMfuUDX44Kvaxrhf/M4pkRmYiInLyy4vMMP6zbc6Ntxs8uQ/EcDWLCIegaHkBTWGbbTkfBRLbwVtM2Q/U089vpbONskDvfKbh1pFJ@N0ysTIfICmNFsYTUdR20CizDzQp4ec1t7pE9I@O3XnttKWrjFUOTFLCzIsfQSIplkhiQh3EPP3J1OMP3DHVV@FRGXhP51q8sQ/mnIgsgNWbgwiKSjLs6yOOaEh4UbTB88PFSB53Lgwff79SPRfmSqKEBZIcULESaV2@LAcY1plyLJBrbzYAFjXmBTl3z7ycaDTbQfiWTsWGCTgQNI@bRQFxKBA2nTs4MZhP/knr4V5tc9ZlLcqI52GZI/bQDj0ZBDkoDfrCOHJFi/0nltmGZcJNwc8qU@Yl2fRvWng6e2ZxH7MY9Mg424@04cPdQL8SoQUYSaI6ZpZKKuGFf94KhhJ/bvB@1HWQDiJhqATEagNTgNRFg00fglSjLnlXv@YSSxWH33CwL@050PkwR/LATorL1all4MPXXQ5PQWbGzRhrkL2VOc7M3nF1d1/ezUtqe0HylJRYHOjqRtGCYYADsyxww4J2jGacZi6rNfLjAj9YIJmd/@7LFYov1YZuxaZlRbaTUcYPowGuJNKrCTHLOh/cgHeeUZujyRC9xlpJXHBptF2AA/lxhB0HG3SLveVU7Phn5OjTySKtStA@pcl5HFR5FCvywkK0Gv5wW3DxtD2gEsIEJEJkXJVUAI95C5gi@u35fEUJch9ZeAy2CprKUBzQhTyPO@SP0gsi6cHHtG1K1ebbx0aP/ZSvxCRiUOgm0JobFThNkUT047Nnae8UB1rnHt1Vh/7gmdvsug/Rg9llzYV5BJO5@1hrKO5GxOQETRw90sWe940no1Qi82bnGm/bDMXSQNpyS0bGuwGMsSsi4jOe2SLYILH34SF3lT3SjCpd1kaKnhkADjtUTomrrAwrgnrkE4ExPQyaybW9dxS/35Xmzy4403ntf6LbZirPRzi1AMhBzJK1vwBAtJHbqSI3C3p9c/go96sOMIZIlfDGs4rVFFC7WzssUCizEBeodYCvphyHUqr9cQ6OT7K9c0DrfLEP4HQXCyE@u3jQSpaIFJ6sL6Pgytjrgv3knOYG34WOnS/p8uwwrXmjmUYkgLZJVyFj4d2yPSyFIlIsx5FMxPSNmZG9fUFr9k4Y85ZvMyT7TgCZYEfQKohZk3C4l58HMtmt6bcPc9c9JStrjUZTjpTYBSZd5z3BzC7MIcLJ6vRamgCnMbtn64IKwxWciRPT3Nwl8nZy2TwpY9TsNPiDALc@4t8drDmyM4Eju21gm4sb@9Pb6TIfHLDE8NcA2dJIxKeUokoBdy/DUzGwh8Q8Sefq52wZja49HnKH1JsBVl1hKLjSQV4dpPTXi@gJUa7hqR@LIXN/TGgtZlSP7UFeboPZ8FRnheYNEMW50qCyjAnAu5PW7NawMZXjj/LwyTJX7RjQEtrEbTCVeFGUxgWth1S0ashe761uZtHUB17jCz05sM2g89I/D0CCLYSKPpeSWUg8bSZy@Be@pyz1se@7M8Fg7H3p5WqQEzn5ZHXjfcvmZYQCHOczNA58ISso6CtV/2Ro1/nqn77zesnWk/zISrUioLcqSgxOxxtsKtHwn8Z4lMeC7n90Kgs3v7UYT/oSNLL4nwj40ETA3nhn2G04DKIarjP255mOPSyXPlyz0ZYj8c/lYhwjB@FpI3cPII@7iw/JCxTECUtt65W5c/xdN8/fiyOnlnkzHJnSP5nrmOyS0kCUFjl4p4rpABN5HI7VdOHq7c0fufyWXZywcV6Z9jVdOM8Ps6AlAlt5AZMLPSr8lqYfcZojrKOMeo4/Hfp0kySpsM2g8paggPtlnE9m4xM5PhmUVqGEn2ssHiAhf@Th6sevn5pX/pWKH9iIC2uLeNEZhmaxQLSszN1MSzrREO0JBHv9Zd/jmzXv6bm4xF@oEM84ueCS741kR6M4A78JjmxxEur91Tw6PuX74/Qg@zxZWF9kM3waLkRFeYK@hUpmcqRLs476mxMcbsi9XntWR5vssQ/ukSWbTBA2mpGDIg85pk@jZHXHvCES6VMn5ey1l/fAJI9XWXIfUXcq50MCQ642oV1itDQAC3LNwjjUcr7GAb/vlSXZGI/2Lbv6dRbCEA20JUP7NyowtUQzOsqqPQz6CBya@28JEyT/@35lkkfwrQAyURXt/ILicsoWp2mjEzpKEA5ChSP8TRvrv4PzIkfjFkR0/YUyCERKwBtY3MmVnyfGNl/TbS7x9O6h1wx5dSjrq1yZD6rS880cSPszVq0iSR4VngNGAPWBsaycYcfhXkMklC6f3eOqr0JMItjKTvzey0rGStRxYGI1w1wjvYFNi39d7mswdX6/5qTwbtR51wLQDV8dhO4xfJCZp840A6XsrAQZU2dujUs6srI09d@E9v46N/IWhxiB/Jk4YVgIKwDmrY9dIGk5jaIWYdVkyoHiLyuAdBP3QZtB@Onj14Utcn9ovNC8Dygl2IJMdrGlqbGRN2dnMPPX7uz1KFvz4jSCo209RMvOdSs7DSexEQA1k4YhYtB8B8dedQUqd4936591OXIfaDkYEpwqSJy1oynaUepRdeXlYeVlt4UEoWbL79fU8/Ku0HEJCB0QkkaXpRKpaRSAM1njEe1paD5NgQ6T/baH2HdjKs5KUAu/wIxOWlT4XoOC5ALpMZyfEnUZdExX5vvaQM9zgTdRHMj9AlVNy5EZCSXXAGWAqAw0UPv19IIK1mzUshoAw3T156Qx273GW4NQ8TB5PZ0pjZAMR4WDPltpC8NTrchDpnqVd@JV2NSsUvWIrpMvzahxMY7xQSYIAAMrxEm9hxwcpDjPSflXjsk9e/3O29Fr@qP590PFZpP3B7C37BPS20xH6KVAhAiUpy2jJbqaystcbjbTVE5/O3P/3WZUj/LYwy7heA4BzgG4SX00gf8eyPykD@wGgAjMPtNRu9ZmOu/LY9C@1HnGH4R1xXWHNGgo2FYGYrNTuDPE2ST269cx8ASvmv1@Rj525U4X8kyczDpwU/sVYwkjJOzM@yq9WFORFimLdrsVN@vtk72yJ9a55cSYRLY@TGsp25BqaH2CoWyEJfiJgHgVECuNn4@vBal0H7sSyRfQXAuJX5EsMkCIIpeE3DgoEBVI@8DkOjw1WX1CJFLXWwy5D@28om5kquNZsLvOWRMAc7AyySjTaxVtCkR0KeQalTD9WuftskfhFmc4N7CmNkUzcWU2skqrJQvhLZD0d@8l6fZ7mN29f5yY32o2YYbURc7DEhGdB6NmourA7ylC2cxlIWweuf4p68oBXD@f4euwzBH5H1mskmcgNZvkEoNzYmMBL5@ezNyW6taR24Ixk6deeO2tW0mvTfBgRfmvg0GWKvnDply3Gfm2aDjoFBHPqxqqb@ua4Ws8kQ@4FIiD1FuPuF9RedLG9fRuTPFrTG2omXmJDQ5QuOEbj4Xr3depuaFT4djrCWReJhyzQOG4oNtxPGrESHy@u13upzD@6pL69J4rHLWPOnkn6qJH4DrzvC5hwBlvXIgD3O7CjRu/rcaplPmJ0M6b9lPGcZwBWSyGDb8Cc2ZS6sLRvLTnQ2JQ83X9973/lnv1489sEmQ@q3CRdksgvJFzihTK2YeDgw1gtsMmupTMPhvhx@Aj95@/AaA/XcRRP@6QSH3CT/UUYSruEc8WkHSAiI15i8X9hJOnwrpb2HPW24cVma5D/iQg1gGDvhDNilPDTS8D3JF9FRuOV@PPpVre1m/Lmw2w@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@kOdr2lPajGKIwEjdLzUTYkGZLomuBOXYswGojfY2HChMXX9NN/bW3p5L/GAEJcT@kJgjnyNxPNDDuhQUzNy@0DIw9WDQ9e@kmRTx@9sfhr7sMyZ@Sm21JHo8VyMxOQhIif9Kx9ZxdCi3JzIzbN9dOnhMP4r6zDWtdXbpMybZgIx4DlpBw2c2yyCwCRv5pzdEfUt@RCnfp/u7ua5n/4dg/lHkjZiZezMIWRZLOYBADc4641ZmcPO7Bqd8une3p5OddBu3HSFydSLwymXUBNgaMJEk4JmeNXUi/zGE9269@42M8O3ixfb2tIws/SJOd5AE4KjxviIGkImZfPEvT7JUeOf1h4wethJpvds9SxI7BXRtyK2tmtNDY5bGQPcF0manAY5NdZ91cuyC9Hur0F9e/PbzJqMJ10ry3EeaY0yWMBnKPmuNzPBwmYl5yjFibn3Fv29ZotfXw6nGNXxDbT2xLl/bWxbIWXYgdJtwXY2BTbK68c6dP3mY6@Rpi/Qtb3KBl/seEuB7Ojvu3ACc30qY1qR@AzlCSwDqo8AtPKnVwi/XhIUyXIfXbwtYXkpUyq2EeT8i2N2wFO6SnOHHcA@tR10696b7hijpxcNtTmf9RWL5ZSP1ILFzUGdrWaDXS4tnDzkkgI7GD@jWzanFIvdnnG7TM/0iWNOvZs8i/MJ/cRnYzRka6kj/lpKRau294wFE575g/3WR0@4ElV7ba0X5A4QE1yeWyrbGmVdgisDD2WPXzrhru4Wkuly5D6reLMNQj82OZ6SS4PWNIHrcIHqBCHKRjtvzY6iZZs/yqy1hkzoRnoWOhGiCOChyqZDQ8QmEsYf2CmyNzWQBbCnT148@quvvjoz6XRcv8j8huRsOCfmWPBG6PZ9ofZxWYwENogu2RnNILWcHltUFytx/CP2XjQXG4VYbsNceyciNKD6zk6gZrZNvYn@Vi769SWx5Gr/M/yDGaFoDJEhs5wOSywE9id7E2PzK3y4EmQ0/f9p/LV7sM6d@vpBgsgKGRyZhaWMgxHINkZ7LRWPzQ61ynlx4q/r3SaxG4y5D@uQgkBygCky6J/chHC6OwTjnrqXJkBPuiT@xbxbutL1rL/A/xtzomUgtHJlJYurVU0SAtzqzxOfIu6n7i1pPdOqR@mzW554BuHqfJ6TuOlGc6bkd7QNLPvOZP2Vl59m84iFdt71kk/9EkNwisvUTHjBY@GT1RRGI1p5H/Mes1L6UevZfUh9rxLfU6/yN4TvhgUllIeCyuB1b2GiPBFhlwZuGh4AFObzml473@omX@RxzZRZitA0SWYSQMnAhInWE6dVnYLrXOIDr9w5@MoF4/P/6yfPiyyxD@KRvEbBb6DTNlCENWQoszCLsnJiQMOwuxpz@zXeMwS@Mf49Z0GZPE@@xUjY2N8pWN8szRE642H7jFkBty3tVe1xz92S@3PZX5H5kxgmZWbCosSpHSVyOHXpBbP7tERpvk179UFz8W@sd3ym1zrrTM//DMPJnEuViWg3dSIHse183Q8XiCkFmvsenVtbGS4PIXfa3LsMKTZrDBbrWR4Y9hjFDobmbJtM9w1yaNbos94BsumMdq48HqacUfbJtlac6TQi@1OBczW1@k5RV3vxiJoz5bGWRvSITd6ZjM/7DMfUZ2ZTsORfHMlyBIm0keINUnkHGDoG74fq13XGYt@ZE6sXQZtB9TJYkGthVYlPPppMuacxLmDE0Z2Y2XZqk1MoZiAeXMabtvHYI/nHRQWg6HY8jA9jHvJ0bX0m0F8@rZczk8@HS5J8W1A8ubfTKk/4UeAahhBHLHkhGPLGQcAFAtLCIEaYcRfuEDIdVsXTBPuwzJf4RKt0CQHzN5F@wq5og3yyQ74gI2kca4n7P5w2lmHbuMtf9WuuYSeQkjZ2wQBjBktrYQ7Tr8KUTR09M9J31LHXr30yajSC6HoQ6rYYVzsWZ2mk2Mm@sCCBSYRF3YBTes42HOqI9G0j8ebndO8h9kduJ@ADYUqbjC0ZPVAddCQkuEziwMAYai/ulc6x/fMlzuMmg/HCssqQWcBjMWlnkb7XCHpoWs/EBKmvA/1jwf8OWXRy7vnYvM/wgcxrAUwLnEtvvK4QqjyWzp5VFrdtCXRB917PffdoMH92Ss84MQsSECJdOKvU3sTcg1w35YBFOFtTXNFgg8y3Omo8@t1bmdDOGPLbDmlWX5xLRxkWksdua0KjyL47QZ3Fvsx6Ya6hT1XXefLfM/ZrKkvEDIhF8e7g2Om11OZOAnjkMIvH1DIKL8Bgf8vaCI3GUYqZvikwCDpEpxAKEbxeNxBBqbFhYOSJvJP10TSn9Li8TLnX@R@R@AlhPOlrVGMskyx7k5Xrw8iduDsa6N3FG9Tqa7@XwdVbHJWITjbPDtEVZ3ihwJJwxJ0mJdY/sMq2aNY40GdeUNHuLFDw9erIMDuwy39leSGcDBTI7Jm8QOczOz63bGEoJnPaWtNc/3PyCOuzkz1f/9JsNLLpgxMmeq1MT9I@EaUcvCJvRxMDP0NBXpFb3zzXYy5z7fW4f0z7Evw5OnEWZr19E3M3umgp1I9Gd7stQKjm2N@7dIETi1yZD6S2XLfCVxbcYRxsjUqWv8E0KzVFg6mGCIBomM88qaUFd360jrbErS8XJloo3TrQCzcYuhu4FNlmyKG9PaD3RdHfjpPULb10df7j1Llp5mZkjnwimf0nsPrUhUUcuW@cmzHjWyn3CtH2M7L9/hIMVNhtRfAlOLld9J5B6AnqBykVfW8OKxjb4y3n94@/rR9yuh7vzHe@uQ/n1Wzucm5KY6MdmfOc@gkrFBmDgBSxXO7FLHz8KcwgKceaxentzJkPotsAe@LrFTFbGYYShX2NGXG3svItQ2IQYehkty5y8zMf2r2vpvtcz/qGxvzZoROul7yZHAUcmfrBznxhqVzGcctro8NP7l492zyPyPSI9Qx0K@FBzKzHK/No42JUhp2rJ3hXEDL/@bGWHl831YSuZ/wDXAnpZG6MEpOUADKwdz8oV3buJcIiuxx3s@xyFB/ifVL12G9O9zdFsjdcZzXohmXwagIuR6GbwD87MYs@z3L6@C@qpc6jIkfhlZf6FmFUHYtrGL0JNns0ycLTeTA1H6OnrSEcr@cZdhpT7nGCOz4ZyZAon3fZuY4LLCGWLxA45qkFbEE7j1H/7MuQjvugzpn@NwoMiJSTNbIEsklJgcWyYcZ@g4khj8Gjf8fWYtzr0n2O4ypH@fft@SWVHIhQMyJWHd4YCZjRorJyVZ7sfRT38SguMvfz4l/3zbD@m/Zaye2EYcOBOvLqx2JNaSyK7Bx6GxHDW3b08RmF5/tK1D6i8amlinwmGDRoIvkmdJiokTW0g46TJKTYsplGs/3hcndXMnQ/inpMsXzWp6gAVcGNXq7KS85/CQCGzKyBkA3qnPr8yNiUf1k9/tB@2H9exM41w4Hdq4wvdpZFmes9GathN7V2DHfuykq2EdzmK7jLzWxaBFnLnTgJERq8Mv5gwDACezcLgZqeha9LTd2aGgP3frkPwpzO7a3TaTKpJJThiB4gYTE8cwsh8uBu7p2U64OA3ADITZZQh/nRMYM5N1AcCal5ettxwCUmV2GPycEXz6udqXT36yYX6Z/5FHqYR7IUyylg9LUmfWUnHWHGIIz2uEf7pXDz/B@T//6aM6155EbP8ENeC/WkmXuOtwujOOSeY0jWWtrX1L096AymbY1t@6DC2cvHlCYA0T5thTJLx7TVZQI6kDgC8PkxaO4nQXHrtTaU9/8FeXIflT9kJFTzy7QDEDS8ILnZJn07W1i@Beyri6Zj4Ahk7f@l1922XMUnslSjGFESkBlUucEKfFhLHJB3IdECafxYiA9eevL7oM2g@HABDOkTFC4kwVuEjSRzK/naTtmdxpnstrZeHlrnw7EjlMG8aV@R/GTWJ6J1xxDubNvD4cNReZsrcT2fAsng5fHHm8AsNb6tm3H/W@eS3zP5yFrZg5iGUsnIdCgjaMIuvkHKGRR44xZqz@4pXdWle@f7yL1WX@R8vkJHGiRQMCYxsbkzHwvJPlfJiCSG1mhX27@1@rnw7LgOwuQ/hjTEJnDl61gXwRFmwRe89wWSy4s3/DkbAzdLbUn2sP79/3uwzBH@PIKjZ5GiNH43IUYfTsunUMDIm1R04C4TCTdSXRkTfxrMtY@18WlpALj5U3h4UfQ/whAUWQgXF8quGj37cOvrW3oMuQ@MWRskWGWE3s01pIR80yEpGTHmgVw7LmpdYMyOmbP7CduGNcmf8BHSOViHM52ai2kPdZOSt8YSkFqyT9cp63WRWPJVv40R835i5D@KeGtsKyF4olMVdh0cYCkxSxx6ynOA5SpYzTF1ePDUv0odvtRxVeDqemZNLUK7uchKHDFr6CwAjPwiZtJ1wWNhN9qn6WAd07vy/zP@bAb5rJGmOcUUetV3A9s1cJEmeWm6CnwW135fS5PRky/wOBo6RJScuGKo2kPM@cJmJHGXJCVMW@zUE9etgzuDe@3ydD6i8OCDRbFhdNZb@pI@ly5IhI4KBSJ04jz3t6CtD/@a807l3GJByjzNo8lLvSwVrWv6tl3MBhV27mhNWJ8wv/oZq@/@ka44Znl9XfXYbML5xh0iPJ90I2TwbGbAxNQpdGgg9U3wb//5gpq2X@h@XcgYXcURnEnOpCNg7AUGFUBvRCXWd/1B22ndxRf7w6pM5dSDsZ0n/rppn2dGHvD5MEuHOGqfLKvnmTcOjOSl774F0mtv6EYT51FTFdlyHzTxcjwyjNOsthKRabSCoHgmcmhWZmMZhTWmjVj/x@Qx1BtDz/sMmg/XBMUTT2m2YLZGbg4zhFSXPU/sTuqZGtxTjbd2KCzqmPvoEVOrd7Fpk/xlF28CdszoDNqtGJ1yzrlK3EFoFJ5lpLYwQ83drvcWiTQfsBBWdi35A5gp0pLMb7oiP71iyC7Yn0OomR1bWLgC80IreO7J2L1G8nQLcRVxM3GPfFJCP5U3wc/52zSSzlwp4mIrlPr15S9oNHu5mQWuZ/JCaRzDrzj0VLZsVk3HDR7AcinojEJIPa1SvUu3N76xD@2ORJ3fVsvwNK95VE52mW9NpEphAZaqHu07HF7dcx2o8R6oz981BHzUzSOAHIMPyvWBzH/rDrUWYikPZxZjywzjLbahYy/8MHGJjG3sjJSjYKWoFrX9cha3ninBUtMyKeqb8OnzmtTl8/yD6JXo@S@R/esNGEBTnJg0@N40MMSVMcr@Q4Gchw4mZ/lpOj@lmrPx9enf7TR3TL2WZSAA0bvjhDFREr52sjRuZMZcvJyDWuZ6suwKiHc1ktN7deQC3zP2yVMIwDcRfO8@dQg7lC150FUHOIEQElODP0FwQw0IunZ468OPtM/TZ0GdJ/S9WwFXYskWxg8USMkTkutHA4M1QOKiM4CAry5BtlvxVj1nHQOv@DE08cR0p6zamdBVCzmWIRUOAJMsPBRlrK8KjXGdb2aPW4y5D8KdFSJM1UV1gSj3CBTkkmkuCsAnyUsTJ34/SuqVEdB7rsMqxwFNk0k7OFPR0te8PgJpkQ1oWTpRH/4zpIXvvebojAoF6nTQbtR0zwshM8PWzW7NYmuoDAkmR65mEYIvp1Pv9H6oK7Lkz6l1vfmpb5H5WZtWUlv@E7E1@kMbE0N7GSG5KMiFxzfb@r8lp9fEAdurun6zL/w/BCJYSOLAQDtJNhraeZFGlOvSHzxzERO1xh@YU42d2XbG6XEYQPk5lJgsmbSd5K88ghMRVYgDGyd7TwnFpBTt48fyDQ8OW@dUj9lhM9DSvhhuuonLE7sQUtsH7g@XxuYt3jqbr24eW3a4@Fev3XJkPsBwdOV05MKmTPmyKvkOCEOHkbBNnOkTwb6vphdhScPLDWLboM6X/h60SWiXlwRk@OVWnDwTSTlCo5djCNMs9Rpcfq9T@Hrq0ksm@6jHX@B8MlxI@47IWRHbxmCfIeCUkKkUe/4/YcXLP0t/atQ97fwLEdEy2EpJLtOAFVVcCoxASX5ssQRhIgIeOD50rdOKo@UfNefCvzPwCWCn0asAMH8geaAplWHAr8RSIlOPhxjfdHfvbgi/3@VuZ/1KT76JRl8jKVkW@UIM2J/OTKMRU1bvz1tI7Y/WQPF67zPxoM@ZRJNOIENceRgcXzhBhXhkiPx4TO8Ac@OMgbTy4xg3myy5D4JXFyJLMvgcn@QCZZc5YzVBthFIvUfS6c/NyRXb3d58Jp3/mnjl2pnMzNzHxg4YevL7AFypoJ7EqWuvrRNTt@5ae7@/gfMv9DODgz35vg2G1lKm6fZpuBYSUrcvh/Ex/1szBGr/dBAjsZgj@YMA2NPNFGeiJZMJqz4audZLj7wslzS4/39/V8dBnSv29wGWozMqeGVH6YtUp@8lgjy@wkD7ATjL0rV9XjJ6f/xZfSMv9jCizvseG8sIMnkaqd2HrbNDmYbMc1bFscjvfJyTiaD9SLK5sM4X9Uvh2AG1DZKA8MXzgh3DAx3RA3AxZlbXa1pJ9X2H5D9ZhQ5n@kOMosusLC4MhyFtty5LULcBU6k5tS1npU784@/vSJunR3W4fMD2LeEohaSMrsLSXlgq/lGO1KGWDjg8Tq6udTfU/f7mbsapn/oZkGq3z9Q@aMmZqjjMWGSWI12AixvQrPMaydQEVd@/48oqkuQ@IXEguqJpYiDX@kSFMix1LObGtiVEbUPQCCMfgI19RnbA//tcuQ/n1m9y2CNzhdgLhZKH2aDIxx4rsGpHYy8s598927BeFgVPc/3qudyPyPMJODo0lfRSDBMQQjbTLzdOs0ESbaFt6XE/Guuq/u/8ZCzj/q9y5D7AcVOU7AGp6jUzwLKIHD0g3AEUdo8I0S88aTltDy@o97OEjmfwRO2nEOcZcUxxLTMpFvsZgqKfRR2DKzX/na@358lyH4Y/FE2Gwpz@zg4aDAwpLHyPF2jmyqxmTd8D0rSf@8@4rh5dNdDkXmfziO0q1eEtNAcp5vnwGCYgqBY3@Yc3Rs4uCcmtvXv1QP/kwM2P/peyrzPwKbVCvDpVBI4OcIjcRJIJEhs57YUTLLTCYPM/Z4F/VvMqR/junryOhJWqmig5Jo8rbKOgJwZo9V7@W5todRdzKk/4Ud@sZLtzxjQmIHTczaCJtDIptVeLBKXV4tulkvf5ch9RdJ57NhY3aFYwcDX9BBC0/yc@X0cg4Zo4yjN3bh6eGtXinzPxxnJ1mZg00aPvwlm1VIWQw4VmOF0caY8JX6dk2RRSKphz0mlPkfLa78QsIMGvKKTWkLgF1eSLiWDvq8@pczGyVHiBddhvA/Ig@T6CCyiNUYYUYGtDZANSpT69kId@NBH0OyFsY3GYI/GCQ1@Dw8xsye8ELGOcfDCqcdsS1bvt06w0yd@lVqH58c3eyYzP9w1MkQHSlN5PPL4ptQfTwnB2OVmt2owz8nNr6EzADZ1kH7YXVl3obY3HIMElnrhZW9In0nHCQ8kn48fKPcsjFY3@w9i/DXSRBZWMMxJF4lxxEkHO8flnUwE8mfK2ciq0sHVzYux010GVXwGAd9VRYuJum1LeyYbYxvJcMd5rXha3j61VbNvr1/TyV@KQA5jgSHwtm2aQSujpPFsviOsmBl/unaC9hP9ocvH@3VX2T@x8hB1qXCz1mmcWS2hbYcvZc4FNnCX0QmuIi1r67Dk09dPbxbh8z/yJy/njgZMJHOGIE4EBMCw/jcOMeIxb8o@PTpel@3meNdhvTfslXMcmZoIRNkgRdmYRBwRHIzjYThmRzFH9V3T7b2hr39kPkfhpMgW@F4jZhYgGIGgqM@C5NNbWYwRUsyXNzjBpGes8mQ@WNsjQqck15IiFtGx8n@3q0lsTFDY0eOTBlkmAoM@49SFdutQ/pfyCICKod7n0YmfzlmjxXo2BOazClJr@gTpj13POnWZazzxzJxNafhcx4VXBYZ00yy28a5u1glRFiZY0Tf8F1/dUrtMmT@h0yclwmuIyf8krcSyY7OLFLPJLm0bNfaWrx/W9MefnNqe7ePlvkflUUNybRw6v/a1J0rO7uJezWnYC1pnWH2w9o2@@L@yAikyxD7wchxYaNVK7h9rVUmTQKrP43AFRGVnoST18/10Jr67Jy8uPLXOXswUcM5MLkETprSaeYvjsaFv/B8NdbQx7LImXz@eHcu0j/HqcKZ01ojG4siX@VS2HSXPOdEIlRjuox2/VgfdKH2zcrSMv/D4ZFYpJj58coZCrhkrMhHvn3G8Q1Ojo00W69X35b3m4yV/5HJNGHgVJpZB2pLKnlmG89ENA94msj/eHWAuRinpisnASG6jPX9L4wMGnubOFonEQxl2vopwNMsFt4YgV@RWTdHpNdCrSizyxD@R@RrjtjjGsLC8IeAm2MYHSdwVKZ2ZrZKru@xekBdfS19/P/pr@QSu47raRaGSyz6Rr5vLc6VowtZNyX5OTXWTZ@rS@8Aobb3rfW6qcz/8IH1KJJ4pyTvZiQVdwqs9ANVCQ0urHHDWQL195xpff@73bPI/I9xppfle5vmiUm1hrOdOB0hsR8/cMCtH3XHUtOtk30I2U7GLP7FkgdLCoqBvWkZ3qpwUDHQS@fFV6rc8M@dN5tjeL5Phry/UgNrJ048niKdvyepmaSzZiPnARGJT/Pau3LixA3fPhf48a3uMiT/wW7oBLPBybp4DMZ/fuZISVaEEjvo7Tyuz/Ljmus/uq@eLfM/ZFpaIg5KpIoYlk0iWyWr8ZKjB2ZdZ0QIDvpaHPaH4@5Z5P2VM8xE4NjGwvTkMsMUNHbz2sb8h2VvQgAgGPI3G2ni3l11d4tfZP5HY9tsYx3e8HURVm4rwaQj87LwdTCOQ5Ukf3oVQen1317uP5cgtXnEGZEtFtGZiRVGjrW1HETUAELYbFE4J2HodSRo199qn34If0yOddTTOmrZWuYuZKJtKGyic2xfLz03Pp66tU5kfLuTIfOD2B/V2MmMEMFzDgNdBed@SYMwX3g0LswXSrPqMQ/3AqSrVc8XyvwPPTGSZtBT7DwzaWgQtXMWR@HM4cC3UVWZN35byGMXhq95uGdedRny/rl5Zq8X8Rj5iF6zJZrv5lgCX3k4QWMri7jDs3Cgv/HgoUCALoP2o1ENEMQ1vtKoEo8RRnHIA8eANY6ms2GdD/P72W/@@XWH67oMsR9svi4LC31G3nwCu@d8YLoM8BbOC/EZO0@Hl@fVK/Pwb4Cywm3tMZDM/xjZCyXvjF2mPPLtmbz7fCUECwaZb7jzoZpd/kPm2asd9zyv88c4KYNT7DQZo1mKz5YzAChy4StCK/3F9n6xJxfXHen5D5n/kUiQcnx9KDAgX2I5sXUus2eKzP5Zxho53tsfXnMrP@jF9T@7DIlfOM0m@SKjtVlbwAVZNLs8Co6pcSQzLEnavXflbvzj419272rVMv@jyYhSaQLga3@thcGAy2dZPlu@I0dGvPU8zGPBDhel8aTLkPffCoOFZmKM8kZBvn134ftLGAc0ttGvdY8@M2NWF/fbQpn/wTZt1p1lpHUlG6eQgM43YIVlDYla7P3ZDH/eqy@@2S9D8qdOmtwTceRIchMHy/JsF2G0pcaBBN2O4b4dQ8T/x823ezK8vAOTzFVX6PcnTgvEOS4O5lU7Mpz2fm6shImTD2AO/88fT58//OPJs/9@/Nebxw/T/wc) (Credit to @ovs, whose header code I borrowed from another answer to make this work on TIO.)

Uses `1`, `0`, `8`, and `9` to represent `A`, `C`, `G`, and `U`, respectively. Requires a binary file named `f` in the working directory, with contents (hexdump):

```
00000000: 789c 15d7 fb43 d287 c230 f0ed 4deb 3ccf  x....C...0..M.<.
00000010: c9d4 0992 f7d3 2ecf b9ec accd e52d 15c8  .............-..
00000020: 09b2 9688 c42d 5221 a7e8 cc84 3c8a 8a08  .....-R!....<...
00000030: 1c4f 9acf 4e29 3913 d72c 5c33 ebec 3475  .O..N)9..,\3..4u
00000040: 1def 22b0 96e8 2e29 32c4 4b2a e890 d0b8  .."....)2.K*....
00000050: c500 01b9 7cdf f7fd 0b3e 3f7f 38e7 7d0b  ....|....>?.8.}.
00000060: 2f23 17f1 2090 f7b6 7cb4 6a6a ee2c ce91  /#.. ...|.jj.,..
00000070: 6fde 3166 f7b6 f0e9 61af 4531 1d8b cbca  o.1f....a.E1....
00000080: ffb8 2311 ddb8 bfae dbae b641 dffe ed7b  ..#........A...{
00000090: cbd5 ff9a 3d8a 4a92 fef5 2fe6 0f88 23c2  ....=.J.../...#.
000000a0: 5b57 8c47 a4a0 5b78 c4b7 b828 579a 2ff2  [W.G..[x...(W./.
000000b0: b737 c77f 3ed3 bb5f fcfd eefd a1f5 92a6  .7..>.._........
000000c0: 4728 2879 0733 091d cdd3 11af f90f e374  G((y.3.........t
000000d0: 4783 cc56 d999 9fea 7ecc 0999 fd86 ad96  G..V....~.......
000000e0: 14f5 5fc5 bd75 d73a fccd a8e1 5698 e15b  .._..u.:....V..[
000000f0: cf81 d817 6f55 47f5 2e34 0fa6 ffb6 7476  ....oUG..4....tv
00000100: 4475 3f75 2746 fca7 7f54 1167 ddd0 af4e  Du?u'F...T.g...N
00000110: f3ef 9e7c a226 03e1 8454 6c22 aa70 d272  ...|.&...Tl".p.r
00000120: 6a22 bb6e 827f f68b bb8a f793 ffc3 04d9  j".n............
00000130: 260f 085b 0fc0 e871 c4cc b9a6 7103 31bd  &..[...q....q.1.
00000140: 0e63 7c0b b40b e722 962e 8aaa b5ff d0c5  .c|...."........
00000150: 16ea b8b0 e18f ceda 3a4b 92bb b6da 83dd  ........:K......
00000160: 54d2 0e91 e40e b1d6 f719 c1c0 d84b 28f5  T............K(.
00000170: 503e 3959 16f8 5047 26f0 857c 757f d78f  P>9Y..PG&..|u...
00000180: f373 8f25 7fcd a050 4060 73b0 ec44 6cde  .s.%...P@`s..Dl.
00000190: c4ac 7902 377b f7b3 af78 1662 80ab cbbf  ..y.7{...x.b....
000001a0: 9343 f3a3 c9e5 8d09 9e41 cc29 709d 454c  .C.......A.)p.EL
000001b0: 721a 8fb2 431b 68a3 379e c70c 6d76 652c  r...C.h.7...mve,
000001c0: 77a5 c208 87e4 ef5c 341c 4bde f47f 9126  w......\4.K....&
000001d0: 7aea 9448 0e61 e99b 9a87 8f8f 27bd 817d  z..H.a......'..}
000001e0: e6c9 ad2e 97ec d306 ffab 1cca 02a5 bb0b  ................
000001f0: de23 9410 65d1 051e 4387 0343 21df 6e74  .#..e...C..C!.nt
00000200: fa5b e036 7e40 1edf d397 a32b dfe7 a85a  .[.6~@.....+...Z
00000210: 6448 aefb b279 0420 da09 7de7 54c4 f1d4  dH...y. ..}.T...
00000220: 827d 5d44 7ec1 c96f e5ea b8ad 994f b4c7  .}]D~..o.....O..
00000230: 3da7 65c0 7bc7 4ee8 72e2 49f3 bf5a ecb4  =.e.{.N.r.I..Z..
00000240: 2f5b 170b 92ea a9d3 15d6 931d 71c2 64a1  /[..........q.d.
00000250: 355a bf9f b098 bf66 aa0f 8acb 9ab4 4c31  5Z.....f......L1
00000260: 3a7e a0b7 a251 f0bb 69ce 4e1c f8ff 3cd1  :~...Q..i.N...<.
00000270: efb8 4bf2 1c7d 03ab 52e8 adb7 5f90 2c24  ..K..}..R..._.,$
00000280: 677c e6b8 a7d3 f3f6 3d92 3173 9cd8 e9b8  g|......=.1s....
00000290: 4fb7 b6db 1cfc 1126 6f1f 2e6a cb5e e7ec  O......&o..j.^..
000002a0: efb6 e254 5774 be01 3cef d1b1 f8f3 3dc3  ...TWt..<.....=.
000002b0: 34ba 8574 90d6 991a 14bf 3947 7c85 d0e9  4..t......9G|...
000002c0: 4cdf bb48 43bc 0c15 58b0 5fe4 19dd 7843  L..HC...X._...xC
000002d0: 8f22 630f 9b89 9e28 929c 7bbc bfaf 38e8  ."c....(..{...8.
000002e0: d79c ed55 bb7e cc27 2268 7939 9bb0 9065  ...U.~.'"hy9...e
000002f0: 9601 8bad 4e47 c83e 1908 c19e b703 03ac  ....NG.>........
00000300: b089 557a b838 9cae 5bc7 b831 4262 cf9d  ..Uz.8..[..1Bb..
00000310: 3c0c 8536 3e1f a490 e0de ceca 2375 ff90  <..6>.......#u..
00000320: 26d9 296d 9b25 60b6 32c6 4e72 a021 3977  &.)m.%`.2.Nr.!9w
00000330: dd3e 21bd bb3e a15a a9d1 77a7 3ef7 517b  .>!..>.Z..w.>.Q{
00000340: a76b c72c f084 c311 cf85 64da 0057 2720  .k.,......d..W' 
00000350: 4b3f 8fc6 4158 63fd 274b 7b32 caf1 f03e  K?..AXc.'K{2...>
00000360: ff78 d87c 8a1c 7492 f639 99d6 3358 2aac  .x.|..t..9..3X*.
00000370: 9181 d30c 20f2 9fe8 6590 0890 b201 4f95  .... ...e.....O.
00000380: 94cb 0e53 4bea 718a 839e 19b4 9b5e 205d  ...SK.q......^ ]
00000390: 1be4 11a0 2721 6328 1525 226e 925c 4428  ....'!c(.%"n.\D(
000003a0: 2704 460d 8aeb 2e50 7cc1 f8fa b201 57d9  '.F....P|.....W.
000003b0: 15d5 526b 22a4 718b d175 52af 5851 526e  ..Rk".q..uR.XQRn
000003c0: 6088 2f0c 0c91 efe3 7608 2c11 61b4 5afe  `./.....v.,.a.Z.
000003d0: f377 9218 592e 40c9 d21d dd7c 16c9 57d9  .w..Y.@....|..W.
000003e0: 24b0 619a e238 33a9 1aff f876 90c2 e6e8  $.a..83....v....
000003f0: f68c 565b 8e81 8dca 15a3 9f49 3ac1 02c3  ..V[.......I:...
00000400: bce7 805d 0a79 8218 ee46 927f 78de 9058  ...].y...F..x..X
00000410: 2270 34fa 1675 15b9 5609 f616 9eac 2793  "p4..u..V.....'.
00000420: c07c 914e 60c7 66ef d2d0 8cc3 5904 98dd  .|.N`.f.....Y...
00000430: a769 77ec e45b 1ff7 a484 c1f6 b6b9 a830  .iw..[.........0
00000440: 9baa 53f8 5e6d cd0b bdc4 5a32 00e0 da0c  ..S.^m....Z2....
00000450: 1b41 89c4 b6c9 b01c 52eb a7e7 fcb4 bcc6  .A......R.......
00000460: 2ca4 9319 60ff ef47 0f1d f5f6 9cd5 fbcd  ,...`..G........
00000470: c574 2841 4418 872b 6c19 73ce 1314 5a73  .t(AD..+l.s...Zs
00000480: a76d 37c7 bb4f fd95 56e7 425d 2563 8f51  .m7..O..V.B]%c.Q
00000490: 2947 e6cd 9d89 176a bcb8 ea8f 551b 1735  )G.....j....U..5
000004a0: 0445 c980 41af 1e5f 0530 f68c 116c ceca  .E..A.._.0...l..
000004b0: 23a8 2c14 7a7a 8e82 978b 218d b056 13a2  #.,.zz....!..V..
000004c0: 1e4a dda5 b5bd 3fc6 bafd 94b8 5994 e5b5  .J....?.....Y...
000004d0: c843 f46d f68f 37ea 9dd0 74db 1c3e 5380  .C.m..7...t..>S.
000004e0: 05b8 f8e8 6997 e109 b3d4 1064 bb97 af00  ....i......d....
000004f0: 3ddb e8b2 2d95 4ca8 e81b 76f4 c893 8cb8  =...-.L...v.....
00000500: 80a4 7a9d 781a de5e b584 b0d9 dcb7 e865  ..z.x..^.......e
00000510: c94b 223b 7614 1997 fbf8 b570 cf3d 36a4  .K";v......p.=6.
00000520: 5ddd 9ee5 ff16 a7d9 dd6d 632b 09aa cc98  ]........mc+....
00000530: 0694 6004 0bb0 7d41 aced ec5f 2c5f c09f  ..`...}A..._,_..
00000540: 2b33 4273 2eaf 795f 3c53 180b 1d95 6104  +3Bs..y_<S....a.
00000550: 7ae7 4228 8322 c5cd 39ea af32 4196 aacd  z.B(."..9..2A...
00000560: 9c38 31e2 31b2 8621 f05d cebc ae28 e573  .81.1..!.]...(.s
00000570: 229a ff65 10a4 2c02 e398 aa95 0413 b37d  "..e..,........}
00000580: 7442 3cc0 5eed 8474 2b2d b2d8 405f 0f0c  tB<.^..t+-..@_..
00000590: 5c22 bf39 6956 6126 9147 8b73 a117 4d82  \".9iVa&.G.s..M.
000005a0: 34b5 e245 281c aa83 383a 07ac 7782 8745  4..E(...8:..w..E
000005b0: fdd8 2264 c1dc 30f6 fe34 dcc2 3216 06a4  .."d..0..4..2...
000005c0: cca8 714b b1c3 3ccc f85a 37c2 40cd 107d  ..qK..<..Z7.@..}
000005d0: 8356 c52c da88 78bf a6a5 7800 8e41 5e8a  .V.,..x...x..A^.
000005e0: ef42 9607 d91f 48e7 c09d 5976 2428 061f  .B....H...Yv$(..
000005f0: a5dc a03e 18f0 78b2 48db 418c 7b54 ce12  ...>..x.H.A.{T..
00000600: 1169 d34c 9780 207a d802 1e14 f3f8 6c78  .i.L.. z......lx
00000610: fa1d de92 5fad 2f90 f1da 58be 5c06 6e90  ...._./...X.\.n.
00000620: d979 249d fcb9 8381 020e 74a8 0c42 432f  .y$.......t..BC/
00000630: 97a3 0a43 9c92 3b3a ef27 72ed cc4c aebf  ...C..;:.'r..L..
00000640: 458c dc42 332f 9c61 6614 1c11 554b e4bb  E..B3/.af...UK..
00000650: 4d84 836e acac 412a 540a 66ca 5e8f ec7a  M..n..A*T.f.^..z
00000660: 90ef 4a11 5411 0e3e d509 d6fa f213 6222  ..J.T..>......b"
00000670: c8ef c2e8 cb13 f805 81a7 acdd 89c1 1f25  ...............%
00000680: 1548 099c 8812 4963 e8ed e55e 3ebb 989a  .H....Ic...^>...
00000690: 2447 3b3a 8358 9cb9 6ece a02e 1796 303b  $G;:.X..n.....0;
000006a0: b8a2 15d7 1883 bf56 d624 3a5b 2f00 5024  .......V.$:[/.P$
000006b0: 433c 8c43 a318 8801 5fae c883 e6a8 8379  C<.C...._......y
000006c0: 708c a615 6256 fa92 f290 0dab 9c73 5575  p...bV.......sUu
000006d0: 6f2a 6bc0 5d39 8eee ff8c f08c abbd b30e  o*k.]9..........
000006e0: a7fb 5226 d5ab 3aa9 d230 fd52 bb26 4f7a  ..R&..:..0.R.&Oz
000006f0: a55c be9c 20fb 9d76 4fe4 6327 faee 6eda  .\.. ..vO.c'..n.
00000700: 94c3 06c5 ad4f 34ba 1368 7618 1794 604a  .....O4..hv...`J
00000710: b555 c3d6 a443 6b83 abb6 3d44 7230 9c86  .U...Ck...=Dr0..
00000720: 5650 33bc 553e ca03 470a d0bb b6d5 3de8  VP3.U>..G.....=.
00000730: 6fa9 955b 93a4 3636 e6c1 ce56 e516 1798  o..[..66...V....
00000740: 49f6 47a1 7c7b cbf2 5eb5 6199 9aef 41d6  I.G.|{..^.a...A.
00000750: bfd2 3393 3c48 3345 db5c 9500 c7b4 4b74  ..3.<H3E.\....Kt
00000760: 8eb3 4d9f 4996 6741 1e96 d98e 1f59 6d0e  ..M.I.gA.....Ym.
00000770: bfd4 358c e33a 0c62 c1b7 003b b9b5 be9c  ..5..:.b...;....
00000780: c877 e115 905d ae85 3aa1 b08d 1b2a e234  .w...]..:....*.4
00000790: 7416 e3d3 5bb0 6985 9470 a320 3f61 3b2a  t...[.i..p. ?a;*
000007a0: ddfe 37f7 9a38 4a40 998a 8ef6 c1ef 9c33  ..7..8J@.......3
000007b0: 808b 9d9d edb6 13f1 8018 539c fbbc a800  ..........S.....
000007c0: a11a 8cbb c261 6f48 dd06 1298 2dc8 af6a  .....aoH....-..j
000007d0: ceff 78de 9770 a948 6dcc dd48 5396 46c6  ..x..p.Hm..HS.F.
000007e0: d1e7 d986 3be3 7d92 2815 dbad fdc5 f10b  ....;.}.(.......
000007f0: 108d f39d c9a8 2764 13c2 18cd 29b4 36dc  ......'d....).6.
00000800: 1699 fded 1ed2 e84c 0078 478b fe74 5e2a  .......L.xG..t^*
00000810: 6928 1dc5 ab84 1e9d d1c1 9dae ac6a 5f65  i(...........j_e
00000820: e47c ba66 6226 d74d 2763 f374 d8ed 53c7  .|.fb&.M'c.t..S.
00000830: 330d fcb1 6dd3 f8b5 18c7 af91 2b84 4bc8  3...m.......+.K.
00000840: 38be befe aca3 d46a e4ce 63d1 6f61 0bde  8......j..c.oa..
00000850: 19d7 1268 8b76 f892 3b76 0b9d 8494 382c  ...h.v..;v....8,
00000860: 2320 624d d8d2 c008 55cc dc77 178a 3979  # bM....U..w..9y
00000870: 0a98 25d8 efd2 f2e6 7ccc 104b ecec 10be  ..%.....|..K....
00000880: 7a1b 08d7 553e ab3e 9fac 1f10 851d 4715  z...U>.>......G.
00000890: ce45 282d ae45 7c9d de8f a8f7 355e 1b18  .E(-.E|.....5^..
000008a0: 75a2 5960 fedf b9dc 944b cc70 daa4 d438  u.Y`.....K.p...8
000008b0: 9eea 3fd2 74c7 de84 a34c c05d 3c68 5037  ..?.t....L.]<hP7
000008c0: 408f 3260 e7ed 8868 0274 7538 07b3 853a  @.2`...h.tu8...:
000008d0: ea91 ee68 bb86 a93e b276 7ea4 7138 c6a3  ...h...>.v~.q8..
000008e0: ae86 0caf 96cf bb9c 9dd2 0f8f 20ce a8b5  ............ ...
000008f0: b1c2 eb9a 06ea 136c 50b0 60ca 5262 c062  .......lP.`.Rb.b
00000900: dcb6 ee9c 67af 3579 3a6f d3da 449e b184  ....g.5y:o..D...
00000910: b57e 613f 14a9 d764 55d9 2319 b649 9330  .~a?...dU.#..I.0
00000920: 8d64 b72f b3ed 1989 d64c eeb8 bf7d bd70  .d./.....L...}.p
00000930: 6ead 6860 ccd4 fa73 05ea caa6 92a7 2edf  n.h`...s........
00000940: 23f3 f775 8a47 2649 f032 46d9 0035 36e4  #..u.G&I.2F..56.
00000950: 28d3 1c21 0c65 1cf4 88c8 39ef b47b 30ed  (..!.e....9..{0.
00000960: 4095 92c2 b601 2ba8 06ba 506c 090d 5ecb  @.....+...Pl..^.
00000970: b43d c072 a1eb bcb1 97c8 42af 6610 5ec1  .=.r......B.f.^.
00000980: 0922 7f66 1a72 18a4 c16b 1837 aded 8df1  .".f.r...k.7....
00000990: 4c40 5c40 a6ac ab24 ef4c 9893 17e4 1f16  L@\@...$.L......
000009a0: 2c97 628a e0cc 2545 0540 ff9c 7207 b4a2  ,.b...%E.@..r...
000009b0: b855 c497 ccbe 0fee 8d67 a557 6497 cfb3  .U.......g.Wd...
000009c0: e50b b919 e0c3 eb99 472d ae12 83af 93d2  ........G-......
000009d0: f25d 557f def3 c1b1 fef0 454f 3f48 01fd  .]U.......EO?H..
000009e0: 48be e3de 1ef5 a505 b69b ab9a 4e08 50fc  H...........N.P.
000009f0: dc44 a780 97dd 3032 94cf f4ee 2b7a fbd9  .D....02....+z..
00000a00: b2f8 879a 7b0d 6a30 d704 2d5a 9254 5fc8  ....{.j0..-Z.T_.
00000a10: 4f6c 0faa 58f2 ff16 078a ccc2 78e9 7b30  Ol..X.......x.{0
00000a20: 3b65 2a63 5e64 878c ab3f 09f4 a21d 0f67  ;e*c^d...?.....g
00000a30: 9f2c 0fc6 1ae8 fb00 76d5 d921 3a01 8863  .,......v..!:..c
00000a40: 436a fbec a0dd a9ba 9d2c 0cad 1fe3 bc07  Cj.......,......
00000a50: b7b4 dfc5 369d 2bea ff73 28da cea0 0045  ....6.+..s(....E
00000a60: 06d3 1b6d 4ed2 fdac 49af ec47 5f00 0eca  ...mN...I..G_...
00000a70: 82e7 7a7a 5915 1075 ee1c 827c 4882 42df  ..zzY..u...|H.B.
00000a80: 3b61 bb8e dfe5 fede 77c7 ac9d 55d1 ec5b  ;a......w...U..[
00000a90: a47e ddee 3b87 b8fd e3be 3db2 ce17 0208  .~..;.....=.....
00000aa0: 3dab 90eb e562 7820 3daa 9306 09ef 0f0d  =....bx =.......
00000ab0: 3058 b291 40c7 34c0 d87b dc9d 4d19 f2c8  0X..@.4..{..M...
00000ac0: 010f 8b74 05c8 f427 3fe4 b8d4 f3f0 2d96  ...t...'?.....-.
00000ad0: c588 67b6 b4d8 d23c 8038 f8c4 66ce 8ad3  ..g....<.8..f...
00000ae0: 57fb cdc6 a696 f150 f88e b3dd b0ab 9654  W......P.......T
00000af0: af79 5281 73aa 62b3 73ac e5a8 49a4 cc87  .yR.s.b.s...I...
00000b00: 6e17 d2d2 c684 f5da b2ee 4984 b36b 683b  n.........I..kh;
00000b10: 5bca 6468 ea97 f9ab b246 6fec 8b13 1b55  [.dh.....Fo....U
00000b20: 69ca 3974 fcc0 9a22 6756 ba7f b09c 0ba8  i.9t..."gV......
00000b30: cdee b1cd 64af 75d1 5010 3663 5a6e 9572  ....d.u.P.6cZn.r
00000b40: bd7b ad80 0966 f75f 815b 94a0 3730 ab27  .{...f._.[..70.'
00000b50: 4f18 a42c fb9e 5711 c958 ddd0 5923 3bb2  O..,..W..X..Y#;.
00000b60: 0302 bb0a 5737 ad38 1087 2a19 d8df c1c3  ....W7.8..*.....
00000b70: d689 2b61 c397 54ec 0853 5e53 e5a8 3c7b  ..+a..T..S^S..<{
00000b80: 0668 06cd 5474 4557 91cc bd10 d141 3b72  .h..TtEW.....A;r
00000b90: bb41 5e44 ac56 0a82 7504 8335 c16b 7179  .A^D.V..u..5.kqy
00000ba0: 6323 c74d edaa 70f8 04ad 6e17 7411 040d  c#.M..p...n.t...
00000bb0: 4fbe 30c3 58fb ee65 a5fa 28d0 9a22 1340  O.0.X..e..(..".@
00000bc0: 9f47 a669 2913 3681 474e 6008 f2e0 5d93  .G.i).6.GN`...].
00000bd0: 8955 5dee df0b 8fc6 8246 249d a5bd b7cf  .U]......F$.....
00000be0: a94f 91c6 f09f acce 9785 5f04 33d0 e3ea  .O........_.3...
00000bf0: 0808 df9a cca7 311e 50ea b2b1 a875 6c1d  ......1.P....ul.
00000c00: 5928 b11c d0c5 549f 5064 1d05 271a 8cd5  Y(....T.Pd..'...
00000c10: 11c9 d818 55c1 717d 3f88 87a9 ab6c 31f7  ....U.q}?....l1.
00000c20: 5dc6 0e8e d695 5690 2ca0 3d1d 67ec 1e35  ].....V.,.=.g..5
00000c30: 6479 2ff6 0ad4 83e5 2f7d 494d 3192 145d  dy/...../}IM1..]
00000c40: 94a2 b523 2ef4 9ba5 43e6 94b7 d1a1 387e  ...#....C.....8~
00000c50: 93be bd4e cc47 8390 e0af fb07 4db0 30f1  ...N.G......M.0.
00000c60: f7bc ac1e 5d7d 6bcf 01f2 c46e cef0 fa46  ....]}k....n...F
00000c70: 44ce cd10 4fb9 47d1 1ea2 fa26 919e c7ab  D...O.G....&....
00000c80: f639 ca1c c8a0 822f d4c3 fb6b 7b29 a1c3  .9...../...k{)..
00000c90: 43c8 b691 adac bc2b 8d0d b8b1 75af 19ae  C......+....u...
00000ca0: 1dad d312 a1e0 9eaa 22fa bf91 81d3 cb66  ........"......f
00000cb0: 87d0 338c c819 3644 42b0 e290 bec6 da07  ..3...6DB.......
00000cc0: e1f9 f081 f1bf 5986 8637 2501 3595 8ff3  ......Y..7%.5...
00000cd0: 13cb 8009 2871 646c 9894 8984 6929 a7cc  ....(qdl....i)..
00000ce0: 8376 0c01 71c9 f4fb 947e 73e7 607d 1a63  .v..q....~s.`}.c
00000cf0: 42f6 dea7 a7ea ac8f daea 903f 03f8 87ae  B..........?....
00000d00: 81a5 adbf 0f29 7eff cfd0 bb49 4ae1 cfd5  .....)~....IJ...
00000d10: 17e1 db55 483d 71c5 e04f 6c48 c42f 5bfe  ...UH=q..OlH./[.
00000d20: 931e 4eb8 2760 411c 6e9b d2c3 20b7 87d9  ..N.'`A.n... ...
00000d30: 1213 402c 1ad2 b76c 773c 301e b5b4 62b7  ..@,...lw<0...b.
00000d40: 6d0e 296d f5ed 7643 46cc fa19 d090 9284  m.)m..vCF.......
00000d50: a05c cdfc ab1a 7e3e cead ebe7 6ea3 54b4  .\....~>....n.T.
00000d60: 6a4f a882 eb11 b29c 5626 b1a3 5fef 5fc5  jO......V&.._._.
00000d70: 1fac e5bc bef1 07dc 33dd f15f 02f9 1642  ........3.._...B
00000d80: 96a2 c15c 17fb 569d 81bb 6f3a 1957 9a4f  ...\..V...o:.W.O
00000d90: 7e4a 1949 55f3 deee 9945 66fc a19c defd  ~J.IU....Ef.....
00000da0: 44b2 6ad3 3470 1d9b 1b8e e01b 17e1 b8ab  D.j.4p..........
00000db0: 9750 12c4 b603 7c45 e198 ecb1 10d4 98d7  .P....|E........
00000dc0: 0425 62bc 7cfb 5d9e 4af3 f50c 2ae3 55aa  .%b.|.].J...*.U.
00000dd0: 68d1 b2bb 5dda 321f 378e f7b1 7db6 04fa  h...].2.7...}...
00000de0: cb10 0563 3f23 e939 a1d6 a31f 78c9 1bf5  ...c?#.9....x...
00000df0: e21e 64a4 9714 954b 14cb 916c bcbd e644  ..d....K...l...D
00000e00: f11e 709e 8a11 d569 6fa4 a85f 4bb1 f557  ..p....io.._K..W
00000e10: 7192 981f a28f c367 56b6 a089 1009 5c96  q......gV.....\.
00000e20: 233b d5cf 5b24 6292 3b5c e6b9 8b5e 5f59  #;..[$b.;\...^_Y
00000e30: 1923 4de7 c0a6 db5c 33c2 116d ebcc 1fd5  .#M....\3..m....
00000e40: e8e4 7799 7381 10d1 9d19 6482 c624 c9b3  ..w.s.....d..$..
00000e50: dca9 80f7 88ff 38d0 a6a1 2406 3efa 1994  ......8...$.>...
00000e60: bb0a 9e49 050e 3954 2f46 7a8b 7dce 1e48  ...I..9T/Fz.}..H
00000e70: b7ba 4c26 0cf3 b654 13de 6147 0725 e3c0  ..L&...T..aG.%..
00000e80: 3a79 5e5d 1c1d dc55 f27e c868 aa71 6e7e  :y^]...U.~.h.qn~
00000e90: 0dbd 0d29 66cc 82a9 5c12 e442 6352 596b  ...)f...\..BcRYk
00000ea0: 5a05 f7e6 39d2 9c61 f02e 88ad c249 6bf4  Z...9..a.....Ik.
00000eb0: a384 0321 ce87 2f38 4f48 13ab 8d9b 8b75  ...!../8OH.....u
00000ec0: 7bd4 fac3 9829 d70f f8ea b396 51d8 f407  {....)......Q...
00000ed0: de8d 9e22 0a5d 1bae e9ee 34c4 9aff 694d  ...".]....4...iM
00000ee0: 66ab 0e4e e6ce 4696 3682 b4ea c435 a923  f..N..F.6....5.#
00000ef0: ce78 cef8 51a0 8512 e69b 3b69 c092 36ef  .x..Q.....;i..6.
00000f00: 5418 8ff1 90a1 1dce eea1 645a 4da9 0451  T.........dZM..Q
00000f10: ecd7 3d07 3eac 758d a06c 1061 f5d3 6d61  ..=.>.u..l.a..ma
00000f20: 9ad9 225b c1d4 5585 0fd1 5b5b 8838 c7a3  .."[..U...[[.8..
00000f30: 299f 138c b4f8 8cba 66ca 7e4e f136 34b1  ).......f.~N.64.
00000f40: ec30 8ba7 8d47 21b5 0cfc 457d 0f7b 381d  .0...G!...E}.{8.
00000f50: faea ed68 f2e5 675f f64a 4dc2 da77 0811  ...h..g_.JM..w..
00000f60: 0684 b3e7 e6e0 71f9 ca86 10fa 2a34 1115  ......q.....*4..
00000f70: 5479 5f7d d2e8 e50d db0b 6268 4528 2103  Ty_}......bhE(!.
00000f80: 7b0f 256e 37d9 c45a 2585 1926 ebdf bf79  {.%n7..Z%..&...y
00000f90: 52aa fe44 ad08 69c9 9267 b5ed f79a 6d2e  R..D..i..g....m.
00000fa0: 6a68 c7ec 127b 0016 f3ce 8d06 a744 a515  jh...{.......D..
00000fb0: bf19 3b5b 890a 55ed c987 c497 c7a4 cdda  ..;[..U.........
00000fc0: 8312 fda3 0873 36ce bef7 85ba 88e3 2185  .....s6.......!.
00000fd0: aa02 0ead 79e3 44ad f548 e9be 6f83 a030  ....y.D..H..o..0
00000fe0: efaf dc61 2b3b 1c5b 5c10 bbe3 1ea9 6dc2  ...a+;.[\.....m.
00000ff0: ce5b 59cc 1cd6 15cb f8fe a3b4 0f65 4539  .[Y..........eE9
00001000: 65ed 3edc 907a 4c9b f38b 6edc b85d 4245  e.>..zL...n..]BE
00001010: c163 fb24 2399 c521 98dc 4ee7 90dd b02e  .c.$#..!..N.....
00001020: c211 b254 c3a4 b26e 04bc f3fc b67a 422b  ...T...n.....zB+
00001030: f1fd 573f 08a7 a092 2413 4ebf b67d baba  ..W?....$.N..}..
00001040: a22e 2eaf 2901 3d1e 5a12 c65e e5a4 4217  ....).=.Z..^..B.
00001050: 40d9 054f 4bbb bd2b 1417 699d 30d8 bf45  @..OK..+..i.0..E
00001060: d424 6447 dec8 ec4f 5dba c4d3 72af 149d  .$dG...O]...r...
00001070: 401f 987f 3f46 545d a48d df6c 736f 254f  @...?FT]...lso%O
00001080: 085a 54b5 aee4 52d2 e82a 6761 ebf8 fba6  .ZT...R..*ga....
00001090: 6ea9 9e24 a353 419c 9b15 4660 d844 89bb  n..$.SA...F`.D..
000010a0: 72eb cdc2 3b6b 463f 8b2a db09 a5b2 fc74  r...;kF?.*.....t
000010b0: 0fa4 b1e7 4c6b 61b2 08b5 7323 4566 4fc9  ....Lka...s#EfO.
000010c0: 3816 d78a be18 9a94 4bd3 c8ac a251 0c0b  8.......K....Q..
000010d0: bff1 4d44 eccb 9f70 c6af 3c47 4e52 2508  ..MD...p..<GNR%.
000010e0: 331d 3ea8 662e 41cf a188 c8ca eb14 38c1  3.>.f.A.......8.
000010f0: e23c 2f5a ff90 6599 4da1 62bf 44d6 5ceb  .</Z..e.M.b.D.\.
00001100: 2fa1 0623 460e f0ef 13da e49a 69e8 f234  /..#F.......i..4
00001110: 4d3b 7a98 c87b 810e 8cc7 491a 2a23 afd3  M;z..{....I.*#..
00001120: d468 63ed b42c e324 f67a b687 a28a f0b1  .hc..,.$.z......
00001130: b59c 8385 c467 31f0 16ca 7c4d 319c 15ee  .....g1...|M1...
00001140: a22a 2eb9 a901 a35d 9320 5ff8 49d2 4864  .*.....]. _.I.Hd
00001150: b68f eca9 28cf cf19 4405 85de 0d0a 3d4c  ....(...D.....=L
00001160: 7787 9164 3881 942d 4165 de5d 586a df4e  w..d8..-Ae.]Xj.N
00001170: a675 44cf e91f fa48 5deb 79cb 83a7 16d9  .uD....H].y.....
00001180: ce90 d7c9 45cc 76d3 f1d8 9ede 1f8d 5f0c  ....E.v......._.
00001190: ccb6 26d1 daf6 17a8 0bbe a3cf 80b9 484b  ..&...........HK
000011a0: ee9a 7638 a15c ed56 0431 153d de08 f1b8  ..v8.\.V.1.=....
000011b0: 2ae0 0fbb b7a9 aa90 d90c a809 7cef e53e  *...........|..>
000011c0: 65ed 1ab3 d404 b6e4 b587 a9f2 9f6e 97fc  e............n..
000011d0: cc1b 52df 8de5 3f77 47ab f378 66c2 b3cc  ..R...?wG..xf...
000011e0: cf9b d28c 6a7d f178 a8d6 1bc6 8f08 531f  ....j}.x......S.
000011f0: d98f 6ed0 3c70 db87 98df fbf4 fa29 6cfd  ..n.<p.......)l.
00001200: a0bd 3c57 712e 9735 af79 7429 7664 2b76  ..<Wq..5.yt)vd+v
00001210: 65cd 5c97 cf4a 1225 a505 74f3 2de7 44db  e.\..J.%..t.-.D.
00001220: bbc9 baf5 64ea 002b 87ec f895 3f4a 9cc2  ....d..+....?J..
00001230: c64a 1c45 2d9a c276 eaab 53d6 37b9 2307  .J.E-..v..S.7.#.
00001240: 88c9 4be6 0559 1b9b b6cb 4816 865e 314d  ..K..Y....H..^1M
00001250: 80f9 cc02 01b5 4103 dd44 346c 93a6 4b07  ......A..D4l..K.
00001260: d441 409f 8bf2 e3ea 7aca f263 8fa7 d41d  .A@.....z..c....
00001270: 56a2 adca 75c0 8e48 f403 57fd 6a95 2a36  V...u..H..W.j.*6
00001280: 2e00 7114 b843 d4fa 1d3e 3c35 0398 b3cf  ..q..C...><5....
00001290: 673d 365f 9aed c356 8822 367a d819 8997  g=6_...V."6z....
000012a0: b467 c6b0 ef36 fb06 c68d a6f6 d956 d670  .g...6.......V.p
000012b0: a9e9 a910 bac8 d2c7 b7f1 573c 0fed 78aa  ..........W<..x.
000012c0: 1ec3 3cbc 8b00 901d 338c 55d2 247c 59a2  ..<.....3.U.$|Y.
000012d0: 5aba 87d1 dfc3 3e14 2c30 e666 97b1 6976  Z.....>.,0.f..iv
000012e0: 649e 7ec0 6dea b2e8 0af0 587b daf2 68dc  d.~.m.....X{..h.
000012f0: 73f8 bf96 8ea1 5407 174a 2648 d905 bc87  s.....T..J&H....
00001300: 9328 6d6b b5b9 eaeb 04c2 2ded c1d0 8db9  .(mk......-.....
00001310: 6483 744a 9d83 ba40 cec5 75fe d1d3 1416  d.tJ...@..u.....
00001320: 3604 e8fb bbf5 dfe4 153b f748 7f1f 314c  6........;.H..1L
00001330: 3915 8251 0b51 8a3c 9456 fe2a b6e8 9263  9..Q.Q.<.V.*...c
00001340: f751 1cf5 feb9 7708 a153 ffff 766e 83e4  .Q....w..S..vn..
00001350: 31d2 7e12 a7b4 cf54 74fa c2a9 aa57 efcb  1.~....Tt....W..
00001360: ea49 7adb 2aa7 7557 6775 7fb4 41a5 f5d6  .Iz.*.uWgu..A...
00001370: a5df ac7d 577d 0bb8 5433 b337 e98b 56f6  ...}W}..T3.7..V.
00001380: dc5b 51bd ebe8 9b86 ebf6 c840 43f2 bd8a  .[Q........@C...
00001390: 2815 8e17 9355 d79c 3555 9527 12cd 3bf5  (....U..5U.'..;.
000013a0: 4ea5 bec7 a363 aa2e 87f3 aa46 bd4b 1219  N....c.....F.K..
000013b0: 1ded 4ece 2259 7dda 7d13 7927 7615 0b9c  ..N."Y}.}.y'v...
000013c0: 22d8 f3d7 c28f 37ff b748 5b97 2857 909a  ".....7..H[.(W..
000013d0: 695a 4e27 7d3b 9de0 1ca8 d942 2da8 ee2e  iZN'};.....B-...
000013e0: 0b29 3f10 36e2 738c 053e 6c1c 762f edd4  .)?.6.s..>l.v/..
000013f0: 46ed 2db1 0218 48b5 dd39 cf68 8a54 b401  F.-...H..9.h.T..
00001400: e4a8 c12b 1f0d b7c1 7eb4 de76 6cfb 9fea  ...+....~..vl...
00001410: af36 e0dc fb7a 33c8 1473 7499 f4f5 53ce  .6...z3..st...S.
00001420: 9e9e 7dfa 0039 9124 06d3 28d9 aa2f a45e  ..}..9.$..(../.^
00001430: 0cca f3d0 8904 1715 c1be 7839 994c 6446  ..........x9.LdF
00001440: a0e4 7dda dbbe a5f8 1788 df62 27b3 822d  ..}........b'..-
00001450: 6876 d7b5 e82a 419c 8f2b 5c5e df07 077c  hv...*A..+\^...|
00001460: 8aac a977 3eda daa2 a278 bb7d 8a7c c88c  ...w>....x.}.|..
00001470: 273d 59ae d966 8df0 5e71 702e 0e6b c546  '=Y..f..^qp..k.F
00001480: 1ff1 bcac 92a5 e6ad cba1 23e5 c54e 6a09  ..........#..Nj.
00001490: 0154 e2d1 cc4d 5860 0e90 ea2d 8854 6ab3  .T...MX`...-.Tj.
000014a0: 3837 d143 4933 6687 1c79 1007 5938 d082  87.CI3f..y..Y8..
000014b0: 5896 4f9f 19f0 d98f 2019 d6db f152 8535  X.O..... ....R.5
000014c0: bb0c 665b f002 8116 cce0 a156 8571 fe1e  ..f[.......V.q..
000014d0: a43f f10b 3ff3 c0b7 0b3c 4abd 45e3 7a99  .?..?....<J.E.z.
000014e0: 431b c22e 937b 1f00 fd09 be9e b76e 441d  C....{.......nD.
000014f0: c070 1d8b ad89 16b1 e392 992a 0346 f487  .p.........*.F..
00001500: 8087 524e 0001 0966 3ce8 a333 22a4 0d6b  ..RN...f<..3"..k
00001510: 9f32 5d18 77ed 50fc 15af f31e ec3c 2172  .2].w.P......<!r
00001520: c44b a87a d6e5 9192 6bf5 833c 556d c352  .K.z....k..<Um.R
00001530: e81f 34d4 b56b b7bf 9b19 f4f6 eee5 7247  ..4..k........rG
00001540: 798d 3563 8b95 4952 301c c357 ac32 781d  y.5c..IR0..W.2x.
00001550: 4726 6cf2 c8fd ac54 ed55 a873 522c 0725  G&l....T.U.sR,.%
00001560: 7578 3584 0d16 a9ef 9042 9856 6c0e db3e  ux5......B.Vl..>
00001570: fc94 86a4 ffe2 ce4f cf59 25f4 cdc9 3089  .......O.Y%...0.
00001580: f092 c719 59f9 1a71 cf93 023b def3 7760  ....Y..q...;..w`
00001590: 200f 381b 10e1 8fb6 a861 37cb 4af2 0b73   .8......a7.J..s
000015a0: 2c6d 1cdb b71b cbdf 47f3 1ec3 972c f5f4  ,m......G....,..
000015b0: a709 2a07 eba9 d6be 3c54 573a eba1 964c  ..*.....<TW:...L
000015c0: e81e b5e7 5f8f 6cce e9ec 69e3 2c6f 5033  ...._.l...i.,oP3
000015d0: 843c 45ef b50d 7e9f 0d5b a59f 2b37 f473  .<E...~..[..+7.s
000015e0: 9617 4cab 9e3d c15c 1538 d87d eb8e 17d7  ..L..=.\.8.}....
000015f0: 3937 f38f d1d0 e011 83e4 3c40 15c3 8315  97........<@....
00001600: 956a 69e0 ab89 0689 38f0 5056 c5a8 d2e6  .ji.....8.PV....
00001610: c7cd c586 14e6 f877 8308 4368 de20 01c9  .......w..Ch. ..
00001620: 7ec4 0359 eb7d 594d e553 f6e7 7348 a277  ~..Y.}YM.S..sH.w
00001630: d30b a2ee 94a0 b4ed 09fa b6ef f501 c598  ................
00001640: 5bb6 6d4e 085b be6f 7824 da40 4462 0bd2  [.mN.[.ox$.@Db..
00001650: 1723 5d16 78e5 0371 4ea8 e03b 4bab 75eb  .#].x..qN..;K.u.
00001660: 364e 1904 bb26 6d50 0c26 5abc f833 57db  6N...&mP.&Z..3W.
00001670: 7c35 ffd2 c5ca 40b3 2c51 fb42 dc40 e4c6  |5....@.,Q.B.@..
00001680: af49 ce88 f80e ea7b 3ffd e5b5 b5d1 24d9  .I.....{?.....$.
00001690: e3d9 4d45 f223 d838 8d1a a555 262e ceb9  ..ME.#.8...U&...
000016a0: 625e 0503 e83d 4b46 0435 216a 8815 d83e  b^...=KF.5!j...>
000016b0: b3ea 419a e2cc 13d6 1cca d17c 4002 a98f  ..A........|@...
000016c0: 0286 918e 0fb4 8ed4 8236 37b2 9d10 129e  .........67.....
000016d0: 0734 e581 c13e 3022 844a e419 061d c034  .4...>0".J.....4
000016e0: 8973 f072 253e 3cbc 3c4e 23a8 c258 9174  .s.r%><.<N#..X.t
000016f0: 84ab b48d 1f8d 2f30 f45c 31dc 7169 4b32  ....../0.\1.qiK2
00001700: e3cc a144 df47 c139 4063 b036 5448 eab9  ...D.G.9@c.6TH..
00001710: 5e10 361f 26fe e770 3e26 753f 737f 6b20  ^.6.&..p>&u?s.k 
00001720: 8503 5ee0 b56e 51f8 3552 cad8 ae38 b46b  ..^..nQ.5R...8.k
00001730: 6aee 792e 81cb 0d0c f4d5 68b9 cdd4 f06c  j.y.......h....l
00001740: 8c3c a090 1eb6 8bb7 964e ca02 29a1 450e  .<.......N..).E.
00001750: 045f 8cc5 1405 0203 102b 1d20 dd79 62fd  ._.......+. .yb.
00001760: ab1b 2cf9 4437 4ed2 97eb 43ef 76c8 185b  ..,.D7N...C.v..[
00001770: edea 6d19 6479 b52d 22bf 245d 9bef d2a2  ..m.dy.-".$]....
00001780: 498f ba45 987b f984 1237 60ee fcd7 7a95  I..E.{...7`...z.
00001790: fac9 7733 3321 b303 6be9 2e76 87fa bbad  ..w33!..k..v....
000017a0: 70c2 4d2b 487b e490 27b6 9ed0 8479 72fc  p.M+H{..'....yr.
000017b0: bcd1 ef25 dd0d 4df5 2f22 cb78 ce9b a1f9  ...%..M./".x....
000017c0: 9c84 626c 9c79 7e24 4de8 29e8 f380 b051  ..bl.y~$M.)....Q
000017d0: cedb f0e6 23d4 e259 d9fd ee55 95c6 d115  ....#..Y...U....
000017e0: 139d 2174 fb06 5027 ee3a b433 1e7c 0381  ..!t..P'.:.3.|..
000017f0: c6fd e030 a57c 93cc 2375 9d88 befd 9806  ...0.|..#u......
00001800: eb1c fbbc 6283 f465 bdc2 df3a e82c ead5  ....b..e...:.,..
00001810: 6fd6 2c0f 209d 7ced d80d 46db 9a51 f62f  o.,. .|...F..Q./
00001820: cb94 e7c1 9114 925b f759 f6f3 835a f07d  .......[.Y...Z.}
00001830: 1927 0ec1 3c8d a9e7 4959 5de9 c87d dc08  .'..<...IY]..}..
00001840: 5c10 3e91 7fbe 4e19 1c01 4cfd afb2 f98f  \.>...N...L.....
00001850: 1f54 9f8b 7f0f fee7 1da7 e52b 1706 9606  .T.........+....
00001860: 44fc ef4b c26c 6e3c e1d6 0eae f044 e0c3  D..K.ln<.....D..
00001870: 298c 650b d3e6 b198 b27c f121 c075 49ca  ).e......|.!.uI.
00001880: 0eec dc01 ef9c 5c0d bfa4 945f ad50 c147  ......\...._.P.G
00001890: ba0a 58bd fbf0 b6ce cd29 706e 1c46 5d07  ..X......)pn.F].
000018a0: d2d8 5c3b d5cb 96d3 c9a6 057b 8108 2787  ..\;.......{..'.
000018b0: 1839 e9e5 c226 eca5 64db 4d56 42c4 be61  .9...&..d.MVB..a
000018c0: e324 e145 feee 0839 4da2 4130 3061 3368  .$.E...9M.A00a3h
000018d0: fb51 537c 36b5 3b0b 6190 602d 99f2 6805  .QS|6.;.a.`-..h.
000018e0: 932a 615d 1160 8d60 6be8 df3e b27e df6d  .*a].`.`k..>.~.m
000018f0: c98f a2dc 8438 85b9 9f9d 4e58 1987 8f34  .....8....NX...4
00001900: 9dd3 779f c6b0 b31b a47f 2ec9 1a16 d738  ..w............8
00001910: 5686 6d00 0c7e 7c4c de2a 0ebb 70d9 fe6b  V.m..~|L.*..p..k
00001920: 7a8f e85a 4e4a 8167 7162 c884 4f07 7ef1  z..ZNJ.gqb..O.~.
00001930: 9d38 ee20 9d6c b095 bcd4 a71b 124f a30b  .8. .l.......O..
00001940: 9c1c a94d da07 a7ee 1dba db13 f836 dafe  ...M.........6..
00001950: aea0 4875 ee89 0ed2 1734 f2cc 9bfc 44b1  ..Hu.....4....D.
00001960: eb97 2750 37d5 8191 0583 fe8d e525 0770  ..'P7........%.p
00001970: 78c7 527f 70d1 c797 9a61 2916 4517 6977  x.R.p....a).E.iw
00001980: faed 3ed7 7af3 8e07 f60c c6ee 3daa 9cd5  ..>.z.......=...
00001990: ca67 72fc afff f2ee a1c9 59d9 e3ce c4b8  .gr.......Y.....
000019a0: 74d9 f180 c73b 68db 8de2 37e6 3a27 b247  t....;h...7.:'.G
000019b0: 7e2a 9a78 f2f3 bdaa 9fb9 a988 e867 1f9a  ~*.x.........g..
000019c0: 51e1 3736 559d d396 d6e8 d31f 7a9d 0aea  Q.76U.......z...
000019d0: d7fc 63d7 4623 b767 a4da 96ac 1f14 0f76  ..c.F#.g.......v
000019e0: 704c 0e36 e2d0 e3d1 a8f6 5aad cb93 b5b4  pL.6......Z.....
000019f0: 8d15 7aab deed b00e a257 4a6a 9554 cef3  ..z......WJj.T..
00001a00: 0e5f de4b 5e9f bc07 1593 3b4b 25f0 aaf2  ._.K^.....;K%...
00001a10: c270 b798 b54f a9a5 82c2 8cfa 52bd eaad  .p...O......R...
00001a20: 5882 536e dbc9 6186 bd81 99e0 afa3 03bb  X.Sn..a.........
00001a30: 45ab fda0 0ab8 8a16 7cdd d617 f33f 771b  E.......|....?w.
00001a40: 32bc 97e7 da98 607f 5887 762f 0ce2 02f8  2.....`.X.v/....
00001a50: df6e 7fa5 420c 558a 8f1f ac94 86a8 d266  .n..B.U........f
00001a60: 23c2 cb18 e138 fb53 0800 f5fc dabc 2665  #....8.S......&e
00001a70: 86b9 ac61 605a 314d af83 c751 3be6 fc5a  ...a`Z1M...Q;..Z
00001a80: e082 57db 0003 a875 ce75 6030 1e86 6bbe  ..W....u.u`0..k.
00001a90: cdd4 611e fde1 ffe1 249b c5f6 2cbf 1264  ..a.....$...,..d
00001aa0: 6a8b 9b0e a7ac d92f b1b3 b1b2 436c 86f0  j....../....Cl..
00001ab0: 9428 c89a ae49 acdf d8ab b89f 4498 09f1  .(...I......D...
00001ac0: 71a9 e393 acde c1c4 ca57 adc3 7fab 7d9b  q........W....}.
00001ad0: 5acd 7822 cdf4 4196 37cb 3249 2fd6 606b  Z.x"..A.7.2I/.`k
00001ae0: d72c ef26 0b30 beee caed 2991 658f 17ad  .,.&.0....).e...
00001af0: 7a0b 9c48 9967 eebe 4298 79ab eed4 31bb  z..H.g..B.y...1.
00001b00: 74e0 467c 0f68 a722 a3eb fed9 a87f bf5e  t.F|.h.".......^
00001b10: 893f fbd3 2be7 7daf 3295 d760 531f 9c08  .?..+.}.2..`S...
00001b20: 03d5 870b 3255 2fdf 2f0b bff6 9883 8014  ....2U/./.......
00001b30: 7e5b 7a83 b4a3 fc80 dc7a f074 c3a4 e1b3  ~[z......z.t....
00001b40: 110a b12a 2a50 3866 4307 f5a5 360a 5231  ...**P8fC...6.R1
00001b50: 07ea b558 f29f 2ad5 83cd 27bf bea2 5304  ...X..*...'...S.
00001b60: 92a7 b94d bfcb 4f59 a4a4 e48f 2b30 87cf  ...M..OY....+0..
00001b70: 6351 9b84 deb9 6382 fb11 5f5d 955d 49ff  cQ....c..._].]I.
00001b80: f949 f499 4bcd 51b2 4e6b 76e4 d18a 7fe3  .I..K.Q.Nkv.....
00001b90: 9ea6 acd6 a742 be9a d05e 77f9 53b4 dba5  .....B...^w.S...
00001ba0: ba83 b012 303b 55f5 2516 19de 887b 94d8  ....0;U.%....{..
00001bb0: 399f f29c 9f28 387c 97f0 4e4a 1831 0632  9....(8|..NJ.1.2
00001bc0: 125a f4db d533 df44 204f 9d27 f9bf 3e78  .Z...3.D O.'..>x
00001bd0: 7339 22fc a65e 81dd ff1d 690b e27a e5e3  s9"..^....i..z..
00001be0: f48f 6d3f 517e 68d9 a9cf 0b0d fecb 59c3  ..m?Q~h.......Y.
00001bf0: 7642 d678 3469 779b 7899 6425 cb1e 016d  vB.x4iw.x.d%...m
00001c00: 0585 9acf 62c0 a8ef 32b2 2ea8 ce23 89e4  ....b...2....#..
00001c10: 4ff4 9df1 17ec c76e 45d0 b2c0 691d e92f  O......nE...i../
00001c20: b557 790f 7a9e 8221 5bc8 c7cf a3da b271  .Wy.z..![......q
00001c30: 9141 b8d8 8800 e45d 616f 2d5e fa03 f07b  .A.....]ao-^...{
00001c40: fb9d 8da1 6ccf 550a f5fd 45c5 0a72 94cd  ....l.U...E..r..
00001c50: c039 9ea2 0aab 1c33 e645 ced7 f7dc e4c6  .9.....3.E......
00001c60: 00de f4ff 34be de7d fa47 5196 0ed2 faf5  ....4..}.GQ.....
00001c70: e79b 1bbb 2507 2826 d2b2 6f54 7bf9 d004  ....%.(&..oT{...
00001c80: 50c0 87de a720 ff2f 672a 172e            P.... ./g*..
```

Zlib compresses the original RNA sequence into 8859 bytes. We can do significantly better by first encoding the RNA base sequence, minus the last 31 `A`s, using 2 bits per base. For reasons explained below, we choose `01` for `A`, `00` for `C`, `10` for `G`, and `11` for `U`. Further compressing the encoded string (7468 bytes) with zlib gives the compressed string stored in the binary file `f` (7308 bytes).

The decoding program reverses the encoding process, interprets the two-digit binary numbers representing the RNA bases as octal numbers and then converts these to decimal, and finally tacks 31 `1`s (representing `A`s) back on at the end.

#### Commented code

```ruby
Zlib.inflate(IO.read'f') # read file 'f' and decompress with zlib
.bytes{|i|               # iterate over bytes in decompressed string (yields each as an integer from 0 to 255)
  $><<                   # append to STDOUT
  ('%8b'%i)              # convert each byte to a binary string (representing four RNA bases), space-padded to 8 characters
  .gsub(/../){$&.oct}    # split into groups of 2 characters (i.e. one RNA base), then interpret each group (last regex match $&) as an octal number and convert it to decimal (noting that padding spaces in $& will be treated as zeros)
};
$><<?1*31                # append '1111111111111111111111111111111' to STDOUT
```

#### Choosing the encoding bits

It turns out that the size of `f` is weakly dependent on the choice of bits used to represent each base:

```
+----+----+----+----+------+
| A  | C  | G  | U  |  f   |
+----+----+----+----+------+
| 00 | 01 | 10 | 11 | 7309 |
| 00 | 01 | 11 | 10 | 7311 |
| 00 | 10 | 01 | 11 | 7309 |
| 00 | 10 | 11 | 01 | 7311 |
| 00 | 11 | 01 | 10 | 7311 |
| 00 | 11 | 10 | 01 | 7312 |
| 01 | 00 | 10 | 11 | 7308 |
| 01 | 00 | 11 | 10 | 7311 |
| 01 | 10 | 00 | 11 | 7310 |
| 01 | 10 | 11 | 00 | 7309 |
| 01 | 11 | 00 | 10 | 7311 |
| 01 | 11 | 10 | 00 | 7311 |
| 10 | 00 | 01 | 11 | 7311 |
| 10 | 00 | 11 | 01 | 7311 |
| 10 | 01 | 00 | 11 | 7309 |
| 10 | 01 | 11 | 00 | 7310 |
| 10 | 11 | 00 | 01 | 7311 |
| 10 | 11 | 01 | 00 | 7308 |
| 11 | 00 | 01 | 10 | 7312 |
| 11 | 00 | 10 | 01 | 7311 |
| 11 | 01 | 00 | 10 | 7311 |
| 11 | 01 | 10 | 00 | 7310 |
| 11 | 10 | 00 | 01 | 7311 |
| 11 | 10 | 01 | 00 | 7309 |
+----+----+----+----+------+
```

Thus our choice of encoding bits yields the optimum file size.

#### Why are the last 31 bases handled specially?

The last 31 bases are handled specially because we are encoding 4 bases per byte, yet the RNA sequence consists of 29,903 bases, which is not a multiple of 4. Thus we must either (i) leave some bases out of the encoding process or (ii) pad the last byte with 2 dummy bits. We choose the former approach because it results in shorter code. Sensible choices are the last 3, 7, 11, 15, 19, 23, 27, or 31 bases, because (i) these bases are all `A`s and so are easily appended, and (ii) the size of the sequence to be encoded is then a multiple of 4. The optimal choice is 31: each lower value successively increases the size of `f` by a byte, but the size of the decoding program either doesn't change (for 11, 15, 19, 23, or 27) or decreases by only a byte (for 3 or 7).

---

## Original answer: [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/) -p, 11,793 bytes

My first, rather naive, attempt at answering a [kolmogorov-complexity](/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity) challenge. I had fun nutting it out but it's clearly not competitive. You can read all about it in my [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/205878/92901) to a virtually identical question that was closed.

Comment: Nice, I was looking to do something similar before I saw your answer. `*''` this only converts to string I guess. What does `'%x'%$&` do?

Comment: @akostadinov I've added an explanation to the answer. You're right about `*''`. `'%x'%$&` consists of two parts. `$&` is the last matched string returned by `gsub`; here this is a 2-digit binary string representing a single RNA base. `'%'` is a short form of `sprintf`, which is used to convert between string formats. The format specifier `x` causes the argument (`$&`) to be converted to hex.

Comment: My previous comment is now outdated - I've switched from hex to decimal (via octal) to save 2 bytes.

Answer (score 9):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <sup><s>10,667</s></sup> 10130 Bytes

This code is *completely standalone* and requires no files or inputs.

```
b="fa9usLQpqGkcGLBgzDmz1MqlcvagD352jVNH5tEjI40quejbsDTCJYlncBzgwEpNLl1BA3xJRggoizpvTR93kWpqX8ZPDQFvGSWciTOjJv6Dvi9BST5TlFLFmMT889Lgm-lyizqmFIxFLnmnCapTv6yjCi6KD1HGlw8EBcEkyFyDr9C59omjSpHy0VBtFCYjFDPDQyD=Sbkn-uRG9zzBqWVqqpoFFOtuVUSza2fCLpSS5FICAuCmvymaNWIqitJFDsRCjH7C5qVp-eIBKDSqGLNFQCFKQzC3HqmPzolEFqowhIv2Sij8LrCIqZ=DeNNRCiC4CbEx0I8lwCaZKCf4YkvCbqf-aWfCILGF8hAavDfALawHbGYrykd9CaWa5CFLr=tbBgDKAnE2kaChGOb3PwczHW3CyxFCcwh4Y=SvDqoIxSfxFICWvYqmpEIsxFuLkOaEDDqbuxAohyGwmnpkC4tzESeOqCgFLWcHzBq=FBIrELFpND1MuDFxOqG3EKx9AlEtUqHpxqOspDDFmpwSpzqCGPzCbjOamWnGHGrDFCLqjqCmXUHrv-gvwEwIdEvD8cDWpv8uqofGibDCgNFqvqnsapaoqapENWrFCiWgbjZAzuEfEgm-EBDDlgbvMRIzCcEyawD7DviW-UrcbjmFbwi0wjZjHCErX1IgCv-sqGznDb-KHspFDDy1Yw435cqHLFIDuCajGkTPCx5CmW1q8pDm1ztmVx8bDqfrMcNExCbDVFibDINEa8bq8ZDyYfLq5Daqfv-v3ECMrHrFFoqjqoLWvpCcfDI4Ma=f0Ja3DqgJmmcFPjH6zaoQambrLLm=mcjAImn1cm8nDLWcFCvikfmikstCoDCoAf9FsknxrqV5r15SbGmIma0NEPEkqrX9caGsLIjGpVEkca9svFCCIDXmn4puGZDWrIvCjCCdXCqnjqCW3MEKsnCjVsmnaC1UNDD-mEDHacv4kngCfjskj=HCvmC3Zr-seKLfCC2FC1qf-wir0xwvKQAmC8CmmpCxCmmm1C6gcyeC0FsCmCuOpqkv8fFEIwEEzykCmm4mmmx1mCCtyicDFyimVJC8GyYcsrycbDC9ykyfmX8jsknDyYrCnWtvtFuvajsCGDeHqaEmHD8moqa9akcn9DqEoGDuPqiFppDEpoLaq-sqGEH4nCgCCuHosqFkjqn=FtxDvdViGzEqiNzyDDVQaDqGpCmHyjzqZEuCavqy4SnzjEkffgoFrvFECQriwvdnxDmsDBIaDKLoDLCqazKCGjDwdLv8bWZCa4nCiaXUCXAqm8nq6frcCdqkwnCiZaimCqWbGoxDCmnsccz8mcq1PImaL1jurCHqFGzyAmwEIzDtCHCHIvLaWmEAern=CDDym=DvcED9rksqa-FFIsCb5oWovZan6cmGurcIuQ=y=vaFuIDm8-aYn5qa3qdELuHzkgrrMqCW4mbzFcDwxWv7mb5EiEmmclGfb6DND8cqoHnwcri7qeq=rqbim=D9CuFEtfuLuIJqccDo2jrGIjqSzaCczDsb6jFKDciFLav8moEB0rZgzGn6osnwDwwkCEDso0qFuzswwwqckCmivrCcHMjEFwKqmx2KwFigsijprmfzqZpCqdDeuItqAsIfOPmFCnrILCGzqYjzwvZmnZYrq91scnmGHqPOI4nD8H2bYeFii1FAcuv8FoCDsqbakyqwiCpqcfuDvkqCCIzlDC-vC0KOIcCAtvz=t0H2ofayIqa3WeQinqFvcwrqh-mqGNuzEIEf1cjOibm1W1qAkEzimEuuJod-FCoEqLxEjrLoKNqqYnpC1pCDtmcbZuL1yiEGvmwxGdnLWT93qcxFii4YcPq=DmoDr0H=IjwuCifqWpDyXkxs3Fqiosaeznii82kvDrX2okkEy0Cjq4FsfsxEtC0IFquO3FyKqircwqmcv0xHmVEvjsa2MmeGpArs8DvKGmaJuIccHaknsuqf8FDDxsmbCQq18GuuqWmGwuvIm4kbCzDkaOkeAaUdLSqvq1DhCqrGfECCvaO1cFuqWkEwdm5qnsfvQCLaFCD9-rCuqiKIkMvqWpoqf1iqkrDx4DqGEcqqoI0qkasN3rlxzxZIaknCcgaw1CDjW2m8U4=b8qzENSmzaknMCmnn8aAsHiWmTzC3qDWcsSnDpmHrjqkoaqtvabsmm9FOImzb-EuDmGwtzsrqWkqCfgtnfpvWcPEsyFvoEDqtDQx8sroquEq6vzqGnDtscsqHnsl3vaRDxsqur6uvLsvf5if3svstdsawtbqogr6YsroaWsDqZDVqfxzm-wfquvW2kqvwqjXarrbx1vjfdDxPpwvbKMcUEvpDvb2qvpH6wuNsFuJmpKvWMsqDIrEcKNsFwrkxtDxztFvmwvmIKAwvmcribsHwgvqh8vcEvFLnEm31v-erzvIt1vKDjFf-EbH4f1vJKvEnivrtqwx5r31bbqzDib-QXwor9tb0HLLEgfuuDhWduD4DDmVxqwgcxrX3uGlqtocdnShscrDqFDtd2LuDKEqFpqpLxGjiGxWxDqxCsfNEFtsfrtCCnEZmL2ji1qdkbaAsCO2wuHTCtDsnWWFwHOzuLCqoFyaYuCdiwzMyvDqLmGPZoqqIqpwf6rqDrnvCFqgahCmggEago2DuKJy5r3ykrj1jmy-fn2CDFCtE8nEnqb1CEuTqs1wgcvqTkb8ajGcjnEcEmoCjEaWD2LmGDLgsvrwooB4p1DCwmDmcqmDDChzqf2iygCHmnsFStxqqKr5IKqGnCaHYkRCPFExrCNtE7yrqE49oadyGHEvXhWTqmvH2f2CijlaibltEEqaWqLkvq1YhEcstinDqDDccaXojq=FqbDqqx1W41bqnsjD1PvDEErvKvbckDyDH2qisCLwdCbHpeG-rCFFDIBCHogsmsxvEqGiECvCIh1tO7FFtusqCGoxQfXEEnHcdmn=vDT6Fv6FIXflIcqFCLv4vLktnvtEnFqHNuIkgajrm0ICLEcgoxDv-EChsbvqmEwFq6nkexuCsGDjmpwDEuCdvlQCIluD5H8FMrryfAqIKPCpwDtn9ccvCwC0Nt4VIxCdgmoFDxDgstFth9jqGCuuJgvkpnvNFDmEDavjsqr1skjbykrFEv8HgogrnoFFrDorTnchPEKKvrZ1tdovFCeJyDnELqsvjfPr2fIDjNvcknuMfLkFDuwDruL0LYfuzsqCDwvvoiry3X9r1IkvnkvNXcbEurHxrwIa4vKx1LtquPaZlDnLqFDwLtsvCmoE53ILv1aqmb0za17tCD5fkzs4eqteLozuqq0G0vtFob8sctKJmoExxyzUa-zGCLJqMpwCDzuOkkicMrIMoDv4ZFvtab-fQgFqnC=xr9incxFscsjqVzx5CCTnuNAdiDXNIMCmH5qQquCmvjHBq2qyqvL9i-FqDyjJ9rFiwr4axDjq5q9CsoGAqYkq0q1DBHykpiYvwn1oxuGFwkgFDuOhErZ6GvIrq=wfPqFwhFtDFvqHmuCNDMvxuH4Or8fkcFnyEFImLmpqLuFkvDCJ4coiooFs8IcrsnqDvox10UEDraFmJ31zGBfsIczqCLqPD-rW0GuCkzcimODCHjpkzwEycFbETvmr3Ewfamfj4aFrWFlsHf=tEvfmmCfskvCDDtihMpDsvOdEnWdcbG=siON11jIbvYwjvnvnOZsyh2v1Lvv0CaELvkvEr=rrEr2EvEbX1DGiq4EfzNv1v1kwzEIDouvqr9Kr6Etx9X7rrYh18r9Cstv2Fvq5amNDr0EgoDn1jbPrYodcD0CCFEtZn3YjrWDLYjTuqnuuFqEvmyoHwH3-zrbMDswqKMpDnscDH1v-JprDvr3DC0xQrvLHcFqsjy3rb5nuxvLpKvxsxuLFPLxvjGRKLtjYzFDuCuLnwsi81terWwi=jjQkGWtHmELGjGHqf1=DFFGkxrGnoIDi2qb2mDa3IgnnLjMnv4ijJnmgggqf3-yhDO1iGCHzLoqmssCoLCab9wjjwDv5wH4=EDmHaG5xCmb58GJ-cLioroMm1twPAgeEovEsEymouC4-DEqFCwCnDzqa1WW2vWD-qgCfCRCEoH4lq18aX-CyorYOb0qi-tgC8GZ-anstEr4Yb5vIr5ta18qCEjGGHrGGEdmFxDALWHbkzscooGjb9DHkmKqIeqas3CFscfsuEgof38bOi9DmEmtqbDyjtCbtr8Gwkqvoh6zrDcovd-GwEDGfiWqC5tADEjliX2xEEVssicExICCGE1ouKGIca=pt1DjEj1gSvi8vWh-tfQqZCFcFsrKsmj8kkxt1DsmIkqpAqnW0veLrqpfaGPatpr9jFtvoEInlzioFqEcmn6EGwcDfgvNEvEDmEEqouGmuzotF=ikbIqxDqX13siIFsFy-bcnsk8oGr8ymgLFFEg3xz0NRxOHmyAaAqpfxCLapq0DibkscxEqCQD=vsjqaInNsTNVr3WpuFNtxCyjRSkH5y2oCEig1vaV1E90n46TLiRE-i-jnjX20sp5vYgsbXa059v5awKajbDDUwGWdYWXYbufXzsv01dmIjwzcsGHWWifrbuLdXDO515aHYwvdvmeY9Yh0OHeyTGTLjasih4YM2r5upHvXW9bDYiuaWeL2isbDDXXXrwbadYFrXv0WcOXeuU0s6cu9WT0UG5xuai0GwDX6hSb59f190NiuXbGXMb9cFrXw9XweGklO9n81P10XzrryxuhPeukxkp5uj4ZyH1YjYuidPsfdFXxuarYwlWZpuaMvYTrvarFXJisIObD1cDxXYmEfNHD4cvb1uwzi3wOPinv8OK3maev1X91Ov01yj8sIwmZK910HbJX0cuHozmLnvdWuL3r55YP5hI55z9bKuKXaUjlEvy054Ljcb15vGj2aQ9bvcaYwrYv53zd9wvdW8nz1WuaIwwv5JX9b55goXrYsrTrbKOihDXgmGKKv01W11XdsvXDsX9-Dfb5cG2g2ccKYay59vOvbaF9d5mLrrXyhnrZXGX4Lw4riaTb2gPjejGhbLdr6fn4dbm5Uk0592zgDnjhkbmJvHGauxaye66jm85j00f8ioawr99FIchuaj1rnX0WcPILh9FXrPaDXm6hPchLmfh6yL1L5UaHilDDoxyITwrmu5bZD5G0xnWh2hD-9yKr1aO98kyy8X6ij5r5bn1vcfDG52l6b1b4LuzjX9caf6Xdr2UbuGImLrZDMrmbmX1YiYv3bZvs4rxTaHwyhheMzYX513Dwbojr4zG9K35oedcvdy1LrrGcb1vhzW4aDFjZjYLja8PHWvEzGHihK1aJ9XXr3sLPsOXOymgK=6-Dv0XXg0aiX9iLhfWVw3zu5eX5sOLjaHPbJZr5X2vHxsuGsemdKHXZui8IhuYhrz1hLjbXcjyprFWPZvrZ5hsiRHi2uJ51=5D1LEbyJjyumD95EeTmOwuDDaEDsYH2eyiyHau2xz1bRr1Eb5O9DX2iX3jGLsu89horrDayHaOQfnvOxD5b8G1v9urabiD19oXb1jYvb4f4iDYFib59Xsfu5ckDjWmMdLv44WlMa5jZZivaNzr9f5j0TW3NzYmWuHLyFW19aPmOOLcSbr2vj9rT0jacna0Ge8ZskvWa9Yr9X511sS9iijsaub19Xrv3NiyHi0hOun4PiK3OGZIr1mfj-usOiMbgyXZvzob14brGd19hGdrziMJ8OP9j9dnHv5f-K5MssPz5Ue3ri5EzH651X4KDZd4uarxPeXaDnmfeP4T5T0ZDvXawa3byiuWJr2vDj0b4xPZli4Xe12vXWfyh6ibrXxn12b6muT5dIr3sf-YP5GuP4OUixKjd-iKWOWrwby3DmLhaje9OYhwM8jDVTDP5Wf1Yj3n5x1rXbdLa4HaYay5GEvahvrd91glHX1yz4fcpOGe-30mWwLiTcP5Fma52vfyPrbyJb506ydfx8KOjGj1XyyJ-yWrYr2ewjGkjWi5IzDb0cmvb15fkm4a0-eLEehzXmYLrYdxGvinLWfOTpb34juG5Wb0i8MvaXDnd0gj=uHPiJ4PiIMn1YjawajW9uD1YeP-ePdYhkrmmMgzhh9vahbrG1b9sPchvgkUWW5emH0T4Ff-wX2Z=DH5jmW519kbuPuJK9vzi91cK150Pi9r1XiPbbiXvAm1n5aORP8XGvaIMeOLhsa8LPFb03Tedf0GhunYiLabMzYm20v2uF4H-vZxizhdrv3ae8PZUkDDKDXmT6iEvAj5yYjr6DFHHzf8vXs2rbRvhfX1GGF9vi9cKGocHXNrDG2H9b4H05nDX4ghjpDK52IZEv1dT1YFjfWrPef9XWNdfb75Dmd1GIh11a54uu4YawO1LIYf9cPa5fdD0PG5X0WFdwrX4JPDnYa5raeWWuwrzr6iHzYawiX90EKvFbEb2XmrP5bAf1DmvYjm3KzcLcxP9DX9-nxr0baH4wIiO5vXan5v1buaGuOvwrszYnODZzH8aG03yXeXr0OKdz5lDeiTEbu9952DmHH5bZsmxrMX5rchhgy5-voxF1saGvXjrcMFcjvimLJnuWb35vb10bd8IvX8GJ9W0O1zgfbcj1sia1X91X0WxvWbaiiuP1b04vZLF5dUcfaO0OZ3aeMbbx93Yf55bj3gFYsamX5O4Hezjf91DzhjYe6daOjWlfD4OMj2vvX9m1X9G0Yuvmb6Tb91LfiW9n1a9uGOz09QaG5nLb82iuf8W60aiJwbrrda1X912GGuPWjsvjJnmbuGWvaQpnGhWfXwuWu5hXWwfWVrauW-r6wWHg1r8XvnHnJu99uHKNf8K5aTvdWyPvWuWXvfPhYni1acrweiX7Gi9yzdD3Dz1fXuuLXXv1WeeaAGXuz01zd12a3jfYriWfyvhLFDaX-H0WivsOauGznG7FGR915hPbLsahGmhKuWdDYLGbr9Xn4iuPa-ehhb24arjGNDGruciuiu50Qrbhm1eHv959zXa814O9i51umJFxPl9lNL2XyXLbYv2zX4Xyjxf9XD4j0Hi5baFXMffnXhsYPdjab1iaWbYzaZ9vwjsfD=veGGdK5L89A35edeiWHzFb5XLrdMh8Iw4FFi6v1jb3b7yyzW4vuf8DbrL-aOUWGeX9r2hH4bsevFpbibOfJxzArzuvYhnavQLaup9j51hzuaW9GgbXhfuzLLna9mLefmWccm11fznX1L1ccqlcb1DvzDvf6jnMty3DqzscJcyfkQEeIqwvIlFDuuQCGnvJgMnviwcy8L1LkvLwGDsx1OEriDMFYGFsqZ1CqQDPkfqCFDuvEwICW2qHbdpNXvFssvmwWYO2PjrDqqUsqDDrqnNCfyfxqCAfv=DuuOGaGGdxX8dC1JnuwtEWqxIvCeDMy6vzr8PCpai=qvGazt8fD1qWrCFuvqbewq4I6rqvn7CzQy=vw-vmkf9mv6bprqHIt1ycvjEvitduvYAFCwwwpxYoFEEouuD=uzyktYvzfaeqCaFcHsmEDmNEjCQzMmca3s1WgLIDmapbKycwqLtnOkcmgrDtfAqrsaL3QvFCnvqUIJfEgDuExWJWZbJGNDECuwDPeqwUgfwIvq3uFn2AsqfaCzNLsqDKEmwfDbtpCCnJibUAp4cFaXECuquqfkmCvspNTroxWwqGzCwq9FFququP0tf1tW2qzGkvCZmrwcCbKy-VtIkxqFDCpvqxuLAvigeFvOkIqFDFuOkeJnnnjwvCjziEkocDxFkqa2sqv9qaGhDGvGLGFvcpIpDzsC2qGa1z6vOifFJmHECIsCEDRCAiYjCXzCHskhwvFFDJDrckpcaswqO9EDzuy8DqNImnQDEryEmyjsAsx7DuwspwqDvyclEpNvbp-CiDGGMeC3CHkHFEprhUtuyYyYqwAB7-ltDotygHHEKIr2jFEmawnEuMqqMrEHkIavsrtDsImbzkn2rYGYgnmxsb0HxFCwcChJGzv14eFJvxsifaREvcFboDCimGaIOmnvEinGibuGckkbqmvFFvqvwibfkmAgakdGZ2frCmzjvGGnYjEmEFLHGieFCxPFCrEEtmPHxEia1qVPsDv6kv5ImCbXEyeIwEj1o=sbIwFxYLFEpEEfibkfEr4b-ut1qFrFnsiWDzKCWOafXEGOfqtErFGbymMjwwIodEjFajymD9GOaEiovaI5DqijtMGvFEbwdDvaCrPwlzCGnC-Cn4bCt1XIpJjydv4YeDYyifbtoEmbJowEqzEEsqb2m3DjFigadnCvxFa=Kyzr2LQy2okyFDnLL4DYuDQEimaWLIcEAEHxyCFaoiLABCpDLDwaFIiN1DcidWvuCkibHssmGIfD2FqNCDDbpbDGGInuCAv4kCfmMfG881mqevqWysgkmDCvpCHMFHqEwnDaHyambCRPGC9EGWvaCgzHSzOmjFa0C40rah6h0Hx5pvroFLXEHnb9Ybr5xNrYJxNtxzG=NxwxFgNNGfCCmSMC6n5GpnGfiuIecWLhXxvhmgwif8j0jxdG9WgdX5jPyXv1U5j4leReG6yMPw8FLf1-14LL51vJo5AagekMadmFGK4MAd91Iv1EcxNxxv0i1syILxM155-LW6PvMrLr5u2swxJnecv0meehpLFLEFaETAacOuLrX6crvLEFHjbDsYrDePsbn0jzyf2fjy9X-iinPfzWHYsJf99rjWaFWz80aYD10uInswjyYrsJNsyjGxniYj91WH1kwwgsbaf1XZPWWH2GfIigY9yA811bO0hWOfrXWRlljjo3Pxq4G5XZsWLhsyw1BWZi9lue1bo0LLvL5w30wxK1iK6gLj7LSxD7sEEbf1c3nL0aPzvs1szT1abNbzzm1PXLN2qlcqeurtvwDxWLqvtOFJfOl0KuRxdouaoAxcb8ktqt1ArAuH8v2wsbxPhOi8e9vDequnqvAz-Dr-JqLtL1xExNNviWqf8yR3WxKBGFL2xt5CD-y5jyxLLyYDxU0U1OD9HygJaKiwwylEIAh4KwCOYUwta3cBqBZNCAw3Ygw0xNYkgtY53iypkEKdayNxKHIWUvLfibFZLUo3tJ3jJ1xNHi25i8x4jebqiJkfO043iexLExsndCGJhvHM1YvJ1je4ZeuKffhpjva1AfFbLXsgecMefabuzdyKjZbarzGuXWZGOhZfXqlchaffLwx4NeiM5jDZLrIsGZD1m9ii0LuaWPEzz8isZ-byOvHPK5Xcav4NjEvojGv5v5DPY-0aI2rJuT6my1yPaNwgmGZW1GWLszOfvLf174e3veiLEwiMamdiWCxcvHqxjzfD5vtPwErAxvquEuuzv9zIxcEdgehaL2lPaSiCbwxvztWyyGNtNHwkdb01snH0McgcHhtxhkT2KwjzfKb9euZtZKWbJILqxbD7FhpN1KbIOwniBeB0feJvP1sLuGuf6pcKbF02xtE11Tzhdjvtnghlw3xvtfyzaSicqb2CqFkOay7aEkRHs1FFkMmwcFJqOWFmlJF-7gailB6OpvkGqsE2x1IUzIyiFG8mPqfQBpipTAbqIGtJAmCObFKKRdosJlbBFFCVqbWmzJAdh0vKKPpcF6moFjAKFEqGmVHHh9EcC=oLWskamyHFIRGAEqGEEbT5ijAypccf6apLKUmpZJpVJyoMwBwMgltBGJwdawcApJJt=cwAEtb-FGFVCEEzEv555CJfWO5CZGb2FqpOiiipOcDIqWgEEC-wqW6B4alsEIqoeGDciovVJlFAmicOpavF8O8jbJipcCuGix64bEifEQJUwo1LVb27HFH8nIkw=c31YKIpEHGf8CGmAavGmynHv5Wq4rCUeGcfQkcm6qa8GaWW-CCcyoLk4ZiWWi4cDYzzAEEmv8CvMGif4igHZJECMcy-KcyEmOId4X=KraTvUvA1sXetzjL3JbWwBqKHoinmDnqLqzIe4gvbJD0iu=pjCdoIIfwkZ6lVnlgZDi3cb5pZoEKr8m6KhDafbvnn5gQhCvqtLLpmhi"
import string as s
l=s.ascii_letters+s.digits+"-="
a="0123"
z=dict(zip(l,(x+y+z for x in a for y in a for z in a)))
c=""
for i in range(9957):c+=z[b[i]]
print(c+"0"*32)
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##RXhZk6s6tub7@RUnzlNVV/sG2OBtOsIPTg2AjY1zpzMB37jRIWEGgQVIgBj@fLVOvfSLw8FgSWutb3K3DGXb7P79b3r8KyfO2AefnXDr1A0@ihXy1byKd6pIAXf2tvq5efaAKt8yxJhVtIcPcE7eTfqxFhPqbsHb/Djt5vPvomjZ2qnHb2dXR52ID887/MTK/YpS9girs9pDxZyPr4f9eOMA8@vjcHCCgm/eC1sFx/6Mg4Y3gHQPtV8qwPYXaHruezqgjxTVC16gdIDttLz66rzF@PkYMEgqDPUyCzx@0brZjL9dZ10/RPQjRNdiHA7jz/fXSrY5CLqvLxv74DQCrhZObpEv2HDGsP8NKu8XsMVPt8n8jwv8Em5ww58AXz5XsPMEv6/tG2HRTqWvtl@sOgQS@OJ5hNnt9hswYAGKZsM/vCdAnheQW0mtABX5hkQ58AMXH8oTUTA/BWTyqJvIpX45gETEBjiQx4F@FPByatC2JqB0Q7q7T@nqRTuwzBikU2klxy8FRevPX/msjxCpRPAO@f2Mx6AOCYJQ0HE@teXiTrzpamANK/rKQgEKHESppytyxB@@RAHubtC8jhDPoXB36DI7pzcavoXXzSLsOwgx76avbhXAva@AViHhUeN6roQYBKISgMffnlSbQk1o8l9IwUMKo04dRtHmLqMQFDcslGh60pFWkA7dIokBiwpaPU/riHKkO44@IHwXVF1/@ytI0UIm@EsPR7T5limtOKYTM6bqWXkAydj0C6A2vXDXBtLNxes7DOFiJpO1s1PhBdiHIyCVWz/uYLYBj0xx6CA314H/zAcKRS6v6Q3NgMIfrHfo3xA5UHF4wiXJA2FDInK1UTsErtKTGLf6mG0QqQ6kOfStKznmxpnsoCjOnKf4Xnn7lbSfhFMZBPzI0@rk88ZM@aGButgYKFbnnNX9AFoI2lPu4L5uZil@bGnaX9TlPifGDd1RLWTspMTtA79yux9Up8TpFQbAhzFvrG50nzCSvgIVAK8YiEbXP9pd0aVvQPXT84YA8/sG4YYj6JFUWXVTgLzq6@roAcXB7ik3fXYJcgC2GJh6ICcmjXlSl88TBwfAeQdm/clNsC/SJQMG7gEHY9iJWh1yjPwJoXWp9SOWfmo2OQDDwlKIF8Z/zuDgLknayyXVbXeWesl5fNCrN7qwEjTRoAY8KlL1wIWZJwjiHjxwPRQOqdPGgQK1LhzvguGug6hrAyL@bjPyrAYUAIxe2wtcV6I54mGG6vXD3BUJdlsXCH8@CRRuB7i3VKt4Ij0BSizWV7NWqM7zosVSYQQ@JZvUq5kh7@GHT@AlaGEABFkvwK3g9ArUgUZPQPSKjMTfID4J3Uaxz2UKXqKe9OUnYRyIiLrtDAFv@jRdDzwV5l13MTCrUQJPYHddTnxC/goH4AHPVwGJODplsjkCPaz8CFWKoCPrXpANxn4PqN1GrXqSZp9yd5SpP34el6MiePQhP2xI0tiC7MQLBaO31oWUV917i9MVp3CaI/WLUxsxpCfy7eZ0D28aiKL1mimV7JfIxFEKyvS6DhgxGvIxGP2zSFPYbivp@pXQpAjSFfZ0X@ELTBkOiNLNQR@GfBar2@zbvpngNNUAwb41BB7XfpomkeppYEqC1LtWCE8XweftZcKs6FnVSZ7rZnRAvGA2@oM49X4e3jkGjfQD4K4iqdZJPXnzTKRwzD5tuOuJe@hbDTx4W5pkmDETn9JRHXALYC8oqRcxMdCJNB@hqoUGx/qGYKOAcQn9FJwGtR4Hw9u2OVl8XbIo@2SNwCqdpCg3XLi3cUU@ys20ChnlpqaHU41WxtE4ntvXBoMWiWBGlQzay02IpOmA2QE48JQ@x8BcGHIVn2b31QTRw9mJdNabtJL0Lo6Qt1Aa3tGvphGwXEQdXOJ67ndYsLYn2dowdtjWCsp429Y1WgxQCQv3eT@jARg@FmO4w8tFMJlOgqfKmD3@g1TVk@2VZ253kv0BqovLyXn009QjddOPIj9oBpx7TsGnMA/uOIqIu9OofG7VFKywJmGdncj3K/jSVGzCEgjp5ggARUIzxfrxGk0vbmuWztUnCAgG0NlIMAp28eur0udoRW4yUUs4WxpnKBVafQxRk/62k@95nZ@@3gpICzKZAFbRlh@@rSM9iBXdvviq7101VpoDOfUei/hD66iAUdp/NbDjnqxE3RIxKEJ7zh0c@nylGzRCfYph7aXenwB5MTR5p6L0jvoFqxZBMcDP@dDLVoxI7NUq3AYOfdoLr@nfO0V@65qIUe5HFfQqt1m@61U/vHoyDVS0hdwn@l0S9VA84Y/I55VvplyMKtrWQk2iiomUdDZVlb/gfO8mRS/X9BupDiq6Farz9tN46/F45t1FRddeQK2o6UVfmmQ9D3BeB6wnRXH/ctKfGoi096ZCifKg0a@0u0F8Z6pNJlflD6a6wArnG0Q9KzfV@aJQo4E1iGm25c6kVKyQ0c1nPLXSGajhBQEq8nGEZfQaoQWhVjcxFeks493ovsXQpq/mq@xTCQWGw2sbjPCCBO5EF8xuxdw5mqGYQZ/fEB76XA4ANOjJg23FTPGqqe4VCLfT6D3AAPsmivDkheuo6bLFC0lG8GLTel20EQm4e3@2Qviim/K9FFA2CmBRkBLwokCkaLdwvJwXfY6llpVZ8WWTN1ugPcSADg1qBDUBGh@iN/UBlHjU9KAFPK0alCLeggqRCG71KjAoeiWntv2wOhOCiUPNvBxCUK4i37KlAJ5mZPw1zEJcpO1f9EgA4iX1b3DHaJbgNqBfixTIclryWlwPqbiMHoIrb5tvAavehNH3gJAgkQhqjZWkRGk/sAYKCNOUxG2lnZPQJkLMZmSZVEOmguZdQYSkuiia1nCB3lawHgTTC1Cvy1yNJIyh/wG8tuh5PyskXIaAAn5pDuEvjIex1/6qnT/zGKHGS1@8OSr42GO1x36cv/1UaLelLBXUQ6MG1GDh3Ua/LkglueGDAKWFViO1QaDsqRIcTVjsmzqbR9C7sNIWDmpFfKn3J/DfI7S9A75KueQn4V/uQN8dGidNFZiAcRusH38Gr4K3GM6w6Ac8lE4lXKDpsVB116gbhtpgEM1KQpraXFDdVIzUwSs0qBrtsiVs5aNJyzu6XJR8msOr1S4mOy@wQYHoNaDucpv7sLqptG7Gax7UGI4TlGNgBEmulUUAOCnVMrnsYkeafq2aWt3ilKJRerOcfGKpy2wGgxjv5PmGTaBnfAqGXgGtWfbOD5RJBKfGSsxfA4B2Xq@9lYkhC9p1FMJwDW1GWnro0@Fy1q/M87J@k83qguAsrt0E4DqGdc3Sq/SvLVTWE6uB0E3@WWDRgOMsHdZo5td0U4mfVftM8GjG2@nFYHzzNdl5tvgUf0eLyvsQW7EIFThsgwVcqrMjMZukRWZYCVs4oG/dk0hqYWhu/vCWumOJmhqznUcXT3WhaxOWSD73rvKlOE75XeCpxAPESnh8BDd4VfPoWaE85HWKmwVhnwe8E8GItdaAs5W2rG1xf/BT2TcCqnY2jW8EJcH8vDNX9yPv/VR7/EDc4UZGhjuCek0ZDyHwqq5eJ7SkmKKH4nKHppzwvLIIlhF@915@HJDKOQd5r1MOhAMrrx3sVfhCTfRKqXvsWXgzzcqnKpkq1agmfPZLuVVmoJQBCApUrZA8SonkFilEYxO6TFgoX2/KVGY9ab2G7aiEdC5yj4bZiX9JmZTmQee/flBbXQeb8JuWXlS0sDErepdJ@0qhAYA2O89ml1QygkFSPUbRjCMWSPGl9SZvt1klvcJ@Ehe9aW3moKcJ@dxJqOQOAmP@lCrwUiz6atlJajfjrALN9nM/jwG@B7Oq3N@XYKiSVXcJjEEz9exgDpmMJnasqs/ajQaPo8CttLHJzSPE2K1n6TatD9lW0C2HZOcXTRNU10ZZrDo3mjILke82SwlDk7nAW4NW8L4HbQAIdaaqmqCyJ886Isg94traslP74J43acBa2V65OUz3U5GhVqEeLbwdgbWBmvo1vhu4CmJG0VZFcCN0OgC/AWo9662NA4k3YGllElJDsM1QaD//3JCmH5C0Emrr4bMHYh4EQJXretJ10YvjGZ6CyKMaXmnbuhV1oFfzi/AzQfod0PjI@1F3Jd8daMgcTRx80PS5VAOggzy4k5battyvEqatem3cCUE3Z5EA9nCCqHqzeDsj9NP3LEWzD4CLzHa8uH5Kjt1gwgpVZvGl2EFF5WbIP8UT4BT38tLz6lBrETZhz/1adCfRRIbKAim6nLh3MnTSqfCgbYTfvFfW6pFIebNH7pTCvFA3PYd6r0i0o8vHtR3wkdXUF1oxY3PXMx/3eNnQtOnrQ@vKw8KLAGNU7ObVuP2eQ48vJ3LSa83aTXXC0Mpd9@mMBPiER6Upg/jNrX/cfuQu6kZ8G2awVL@/as9eti1ArDAV@TGRYzTW/hGw32jDNlVTxVuj72yVFD2NiWE7yibThVQUwu/JjV5JFCd0zOO1V4b54tqFrmnvelHEcknH4BXD0DZtrYc6AymeJU5SGqGXLQ/3EVSkZ6WVXLfSHjtPxZFDYcJGEmXBlvV6hTiO5UTJK8EyVkaUhnE2fhv9Ph2d6GF86zEcCTPcCcb78ovaTm46xo2NMXXjK3VS/dbkxFPm1u/QaQ7m3TTiVWvQPJb3bKznurPHynounplUyche9z5/4Vj/pkymd/TsRnJVyUMqInF8Zr0fUmimcI4TjvKbB61UUXOcVrabwjtr1CG87DjJlBk7ZqirsVSH3p/48@KYhkfPsZHqOLnyoFGvaAx20raTu136tr069DJeYvJdvZFaDNsKqpSatnKrLfl0qEpJMslE2bv15egyRodmNaOR@NOk7HPsUNsu2lhqZ/mQ9BKyEsYFd7UMGjpomPGrVzHsY2cDc2qn7rbYpuklIYtuZagowc7L5oGU8VI28hm7sRVMlmTkQbfFvcoqt6TBS@7zxnpRbn/XegS2awGbqqwpPyvPJeNMlmy/r/jBrgwjP7CWTNJxsJ@WI6lM2cS6dXc/KB0cyzuBMd@X97QMeF7ul8AM7G/isTeE7bz4j0ny0aZPaLvG3ETltoQbZ7lIk4TOoV6WQ7xnlS1t2pgqzaFrb997alIrGNfq7/8x8n38kttvOrpajuQTXiWnPDYTrW47@lS9JecH8aalLLPrmsS2uYMTbStpra5z2dlt9krVazF1PVzdAlWukUUgrp5Voqf1cPcihVbXY@XFJGdHT@euD@59GIcajJfjfgOVEceFQVjssKDMo59pt452Ftt9qN/37vT8lHa8Vd7cj26f8dfFi58jO/jlmJRyNcugonFaLZ3E0f2pfYxd9uy3x7bj2TaPNjQDRJdztYwcOjbKHjycRgiJjseJt80Wtnhk3M6rSX9LE1E7dGC8ZfGucoN@PDhlKyUk@pnwM29UOEObHlxTOaMklEHTaWNqVomiVm4xmGCmERX3@Whrg1lF/PrSdtCK3ldiV88nU@S2SifXLX9Eu9ua8Gj0ggVHpkPuPAyD9IvKraoc@TAqkjbEcLPDU8t1RJxEOrryZv/lMKZj5khNJ5Zqd9PbZ0YZjo11Z5dd6D59aWrZ34x9yK60WOKnWltqWlS6L9Mp3Zdc2fV8CO9O5bwaT9n55mJf@/6@2t/ZTjIbrd7eNmPrAp8vS8N6vmcxgQ3Ps7v1sB/GE6qYTGRHFzZGZ71dWBnUmu/PN7PizNxqSsqXcs@ojOfG3NI9Hx/2y9ddzzcau@54t8JvNl@q14ZdojDSZLXsIA9KUmVOmJTT9VDBnwe821GuOWbX2LMpY/oKiOWRvyHoIkVKJV@OWby92FxWK0@70M02O4NHU8Ae6d3GnNhblS93qVtPbWO/vPL5cAkrtzLjZTlvlkgmcptNlVtXEbP9FVIj5ZqbtAPlFjE2WYCyco15EsjkNbuKNUGUh4@O7qxqdO2IGuxwVSSGzcsoquPo3dlZt8C/NnrTuj5V5IzQTLL7Jru/krKWnF@LtSwdvXndC5M6vcazKurvKLIz7hkPS4fKKd4@j9CzKx7ZplPT8T6eL45amWOmF9M27ky77JjdKWWxOnGzsUn4@36IXUX8axYGZU8OwR1TY/fIXrnhlmOTsIBQjVu@NdR2xJa3Uc@ZreVLTw/JDvfndw3hRRPMY8@QOlX2ok3YHmLPW/ODivutpL9Vmcem62JHMSe9uG3qxTcJ3a3nUMsz7AbGVlFWHbzYW/@JlPl6mAmu8kjes9yJo9srp79syF@mq6OUSWxrHK2ETKEZ@EnupHdi6@hu3F1bsx5@TTK2znfYJMSWJIuicZKr3DNv1a9okjDQRWmTS7cxl3ebnnITcpVUfHdZ0yCd7xq/zqaZpUGJZ00@C209sI2tTDoSdwzVJPs1aUL4XL0DcY3dEmexNMLLa7XfMGMPREfHsbfas3maVHs@y2tsy7Qsi8XeaEuOzZ64Kq5kesVppRgPzs0Y0Z2tp8egr4OvYm3ynMgIzbXIaVqZPSN/65s@3KwiShgb7yY1LPUMsP36TnMSGuFTN@NK6ezskty2abUrcNITHtuh5WVrlTsmXMsqyfYvElbRO4dWeK22SsUO17/tGsmoON0/qGMG2pc5jUmc0Q1Xw/nUzrMJ6GHLxvwQ7TXPnicq5es/W9q6Go9RpaOe9rNaACJFPrvGLaM8nsZotMs4mjQjSzJGG7mfIq8w5SFWjdecdZFG73LLDxebPLTALncVjVGs8nuZNMwkqZwyFv9ymbOsL7iDq5nH4xjEsTKjLCMnNx5Xw1xf5pbsqjyRTNOGKgMMtb31jIipPiSjuzbuL@z@dky7vNOgJ6XLy8sYvWASuFRTYmPpYpJNVpZ0axFZuTfoyjFlIxtt41PSkpuZpxzbWWNyMK3QYbY58jOe72/nfQu28RIHNFHbNbbipZr1tEKrMjxma5GPr3nexGWf3F8VoSYjEU1W8nTUVPW5toeZ674udnBwTjs7e2Us8lZM7TiQr2t58CcLY7ZXOuTs6K9l0aKodAMglcGGhN@Rm@nAvC09i/aZwh1lNMzP83qS66iSsiHqMyBj51S2Wa7a3TluQeNSR@4gaIjDgyznUZpy08zXJjYDM03FW4svVCtU@b5qroMmVaHN/jld8voTZb6YlP/W4Wf8BG6jzoWOMWxKl4M2E7UKJhf2sxkiyeAVJy7uxdME4hPe61wA/ZZCkw@irfDoq7vFCve94lOUhNt7JaEQ372AUIrmBvIlnwU45eqolwpdoms0x4cXMDVIpgFFYvYVyOB12atVHu6gI@wolEvW4ZBDU0QSYJ0gaTYJy99LoZpfYP1cjmraKF7nDld72knh@YO5pKpCig0vXbCTzkzT1M1JixFqxxEex3Wph0StOckEIDj1eq6Twg1V4HO98pTsejMqAh9y0tHLkk4iGJqwTnkh4ZCfhOxJsPtUGDRKfPvnHBVwRHN0jp70rGcMgXGC90xM30U@@UrsRtxsT73ICVhvgS7GBfEph3ToAGjOjH6fOivFJNbviVFoiQGq724P2c7RJNwVTMLBWN8Z78aQm4Mu9OrqlP7kckqB3t/mZ/DrWWAIOiV0pD0pVmRYhbWvr@ExrLNz0zTVpEC1MlS32nHjWpBtL5QjiFtCV7mBi1Xa@R1ce7AVLjHXvQpZjs/cQ8DvAYK/wYklFYhX4PV1OSmM4RnKtO5SopN36CC4jssBipvPm0@I5IL4UvWnfv4Fx6nvJgHVkr5Rd1O02wAGXfeagR3wag@jTpbfw7gkSyKm08evzXuA7bAUnocuvtxWGHEyNWi8CnGVyKt9ono5wN7ndK2brUzcpGj43FPDm3WvU1Ce3VWZVobPOuSznPxGKsW0hYBxl/ghbxRijcs0p6V1TQXXh1FCTYzq4p8KUr/c5zaXgK@Vct0mqRBHOPBclmEw3zGQCA387s1IU7f4ufdQ7Wtl@xzQGC2ZP@k82x576k94TgJ9OoRyHR1zncDpZhxMgSVuehbB9QKikOQxcsNc6ICOXbrwazVNfvtCFSbVol2pGxLEWi3hNhSsGq6uwohOL6gIkPfpvWrAgg1oLAoGM/Y77WVfykoymCwsp0OLOD23ExIrQv3f/1TsYIVZQV4NUDMmx8uyym3wqQNrvWDYBIEFkxF@IsZJFPgpOiFvXgAmLQtOH6CDAZwI9tnNhCl7RWoENaNe33PXz@EWixuAkHZUN9dvRnBSVg1yfs3dw8HkIlMiWvqi5hCoDnhX7Ak0NZB4C@EU/L67wEF/iwwoVu9rDbmugAEsQ5JyX@rO2p2SLQ5i5DXUSai055tMzrOO3at7vM3TjIvbzc0B4F9XsG9sV2tVzkY/S6OgjGdV8mJi@aEyqvnlOlHxiu3qvmjF@bYr6539ztz9cr1PBxzk5sa0gsA21bm1T6TI6it5cexerOtJO0tfmSidb/OsDGb2ix/MV9O2N0G0v6urDHT23vbTfG6yVBk8y8ouwAHCBD1OJA3HQMb7VCp9xdOZv08kzO49bYxqXfJtXi1OvGGsuedr5CX9OXccWUUER@vBIAk0jdFv@qlaEtmfb/1SuXOjUemYkWfW01T0lORm/LxHkbd1c58VibOcDqZJQ6OMwlzG0e/3u6ra3X0WlnZUz17Xpl8m8yN6Muc9ZiZtjSBQgT3tjGm@mOyyL4LqV/A1w189QjQ3010TGOS@qt7s14dJ6I2uKzfvcXDbapkR2SgHNcE5CoQaQnzOw7dxGX/Pr3Yk7WlO6aEexGCe5Gn0Dmo79XS@lyE7ZI6CmRgboU7rBsrNWZNuYM5ovt0Ui0R@WH7vovny4eJgOw82gJvFrpY5CJYEzt/GtxlCx1uKM7mwaVreyD@V1mUCYfI9DWSXfoiP5w2cpl1STMZ8S@piSOwdW7oaXV5kuc0Xz4@@lfZHFD@D73Y3nHfV2ZxvOiva7DBbVUYFO9d5aFg7ls0BmvvmBdxzqbyrmaizWWXWMxsveV52lSLmKcc0iPsiS69ZTui4vpZL9aREru4YR083LJ95rAtWkjwPptm6ZexqV/AZSL93n9DkOssZgVb3O1rXA@ufG7qEyrtf7DglyrppeWsrV9nKhvdkYxB/K8/jY88Xc7mT21Rw9xmZbhT0a5jrY5m/rGynMhagiV0Jf7EIzKnyxFytObTVcJ@QPM1KjGgcV@Ws/pyiV5GVJNi@7@SLATrNah2iZXFvw82b6hc1zL7xjGtapF45zGX92F4m/WsX6mTjc3heInr2AzFT@AuX3c28UD@cGvaRfRh5dlZ3sw9Gd8z3XXqh2NA9Rab50NGjUkNTlO9pN6shX1a9dqqJCwhch2T5RVD92@tNjOsrn1J8FmGE@fuMN78Kwt4f@7BTtSt6tJ1N/3v1F4bdA7@L/POjY93jRIXvDucTByHFl8vvV9uf3/QDY/AjaMTX8@lVGupyuXcp3vMWV6cLRsLlP55XOigFxzaI@prwxcP@b/ekb2lMPGxWnZYuTfM96YLLN@@e5@7nvLTX6WO6Fu/hwz1PLzKlp@58Ho7pdEID3WAX/wCEVqRs2wbnPApt8HSpJtEuZIx1YQp9ERUIgc0kov2HRd498kWbuZp6W/VzfuMTZ2nYEYUP4aGiZ9alYHTZvLcoYjn6PH9PrRn80O0vD3uHxq@nY7ozk4vfIc/ND8DlJ6Jcvvwd9CNhSfCduWn@qX3OXpCDS6JoA0C6tEFtPVkUMSuFybqeEOLqANTVZbnFCu95RuCaLptLqhU/9F9WfLxIbfq/1cns42xYq2B3ptH0IS5eyxoOGxGI1c@sQtEzNNh47Crwan0/n@rn/v3TvIsnZLuU2t2zRRd54PtLCUlOVdPYxWcJlBiCoOMl@@sPxrtWDn/2g2RN8Sfp/@z/eB/7/yJ9ytj/fWfDkMn@X/1/vVjBhv5ff22Of/1Bjn8Z5nb31x/r8cXS4R8r6/7x/t//mP@1/Gv9M2/ln/OfrPmT/Ofr8v@/rv/5@s9//vOP9PjXX3/8fYn9fUmSpsj@oSPhr3/@n/Rfx/W/6X@z//mfPzq9oeEf6b/@Mv76X7vtP//97/8H)

## Explanation

I first took the string of AUGC characters and rounded it off to a multiple of 3 (shaving 32 A's off the end). I then replaced every A to be 0, U to be 1, C to be 2, and G to be 3. Let's call this new string x.

With x, I then made a new string, b, which takes three characters at a time from x and uses the reverse of my z dictionary to encode it into a string that is 1/3 the length of the original.

After this, it was simple: all my program needs to do is to have the b string, and decode it one character at a time using the z dictionary, then add 32 zeroes at the end to make up for the 32 A's I took off in the beginning.

The most recent edit makes use of Will's suggestion as well as a few of my own improvements.

Comment: you can replace the 2nd line with `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";a='01234';z=dict(zip(b+b.upper()+'0123456789-=',(x+y+z for x in a for y in a for z in a)))` and save 522 characters.

Comment: Save 4 bytes by replacing `import string as s;l=s.ascii_letters+s.digits...` with `from string import*;l=ascii_letters+digits...`

Answer (score 8):

## bash + `flif-tools`, <strike>26</strike> 23+1+7359 = <strike>7386</strike> 7383 bytes

Same setup as @mypronounismonicareinstate, but the bash script is trimmed by <strike>14</strike> 17 bytes. I don't have enough rep to comment so I'll have to put it here:

```
flif -d f -|sed 1,3d
```

Edit: Improved by 3 bytes -  thank you @Mitchell Spector. Original:

```
flif -d f -|tr -cd ACUG
```

Comment: The image file is still provided in a file called `f`, but the unnecessary write to `.pgm` was replaced with a direct pipe into `tr`. I presume this was added because `flif` doesn't allow output files without a specific extension.

Comment: Sorry, I was too hasty in looking at your script -- it looks good.

Comment: No worries, I can see how the syntax could be confusing.

Comment: I added a comment to @mypronounismonicareinstate's answer, so they don't happen to miss seeing your improvement.

Comment: I think you can also save 3 more bytes by using `sed 1,3d` instead of `tr -cd ACUG`.

Comment: I could not resist to post this link [https://m.xkcd.com/2299/](https://m.xkcd.com/2299/)

Comment: FLIF file can be compressed losslessly down to 7280b - https://pastebin.com/raw/rB3H7Fvj

Answer (score 7):

## bash + zpaq 1.10, <sup><strike>17</strike></sup>16 + 1 + 7360 = <sup><strike>7377</strike> <strike>7378</strike></sup> 7377 bytes

*Note: this was done with version 1.10 of zpaq, released in 2009, obtained today for Ubuntu 18.04 via `apt-get`. The **latest** release 7.15 of zpaq not only has much more verbose option syntax, but does not even support the older options for omitting metadata. Therefore this cannot be reproduced with the current release of zpaq.*

Similar to [my-pronoun-is-monicareinstate's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/205895/13951) but using [zpaq](http://mattmahoney.net/dc/zpaq.html) instead of flif-tools.

Decompression bash script, 17 bytes:

```
zpaq xq g >(cat)
```

Requires the binary file `g` of 7360 bytes created with this compression command:  (plus one more byte for the filename `g` length)

```
zpaq nsivc g uncompressed.txt
```

which has this binary dump:

```
00000000  7a 50 51 01 01 45 00 03  03 00 00 08 03 05 08 0d  |zPQ..E..........|
00000010  00 08 11 01 08 12 02 08  12 03 08 13 04 04 16 18  |................|
00000020  07 10 00 07 18 ff 00 11  68 4a 04 5f 01 3b 70 0a  |........hJ._.;p.|
00000030  19 3b 70 0a 19 3b 70 0a  19 3b 70 0a 19 3b 70 0a  |.;p..;p..;p..;p.|
00000040  19 3b 0a 3b 70 19 45 cf  08 70 38 00 01 00 00 00  |.;.;p.E..p8.....|
00000050  ff 32 25 ab 62 89 2f d1  b5 43 28 d9 e3 2f 27 99  |.2%.b./..C(../'.|
00000060  8f 57 3d 5b 71 fe 32 8e  ab 5c 04 59 9d 46 32 16  |.W=[q.2..\.Y.F2.|
00000070  60 58 75 a5 47 06 9c ac  e6 98 00 75 5e e1 15 85  |`Xu.G......u^...|
00000080  e8 de a9 05 22 22 0b 4a  ff 03 54 76 b9 cb a0 f3  |...."".J..Tv....|
00000090  44 d8 c4 0d a4 aa 9d b1  9a 02 5d c0 3a ed 8c f4  |D.........].:...|
000000a0  e7 75 ea e0 2d 37 36 d6  fe 72 dc 9e fa 81 4e e3  |.u..-76..r....N.|
000000b0  6a 53 55 14 02 9f 04 1a  4e 41 35 e3 f2 5c 59 7b  |jSU.....NA5..\Y{|
000000c0  e8 26 1e 5b cc 6b d8 a4  71 15 0e b0 e2 92 51 be  |.&.[.k..q.....Q.|
000000d0  6c a3 22 d4 f1 59 03 24  93 72 25 ed 39 e5 87 ac  |l."..Y.$.r%.9...|
000000e0  91 bd c4 c2 92 a6 eb ff  96 25 27 9a c4 cb b9 be  |.........%'.....|
000000f0  33 5a 0d ee fa 7a bf 4c  c9 b1 c0 96 80 51 cb c1  |3Z...z.L.....Q..|
00000100  bb d7 9b 9b dd d6 7f d8  c0 42 45 b1 69 cf 97 11  |.........BE.i...|
00000110  52 1e 57 c6 5d 93 e7 b3  7b 91 9f 08 d4 f7 32 70  |R.W.]...{.....2p|
00000120  3c a2 5a 38 71 8f d6 77  63 05 45 cb 86 3c 7b 8b  |<.Z8q..wc.E..<{.|
00000130  dd be ae d6 13 75 1f 4a  4f 79 a5 eb 3b 6f c1 75  |.....u.JOy..;o.u|
00000140  aa d8 f9 fe 33 65 a8 cf  e3 36 f9 86 f2 d7 6b 0c  |....3e...6....k.|
00000150  5a a6 74 03 9f 5d c3 5a  f0 4d 12 16 1d d6 4e 4b  |Z.t..].Z.M....NK|
00000160  a4 a9 ce 30 43 f2 54 16  dd 34 8f 13 65 d9 0b 84  |...0C.T..4..e...|
00000170  71 40 45 ca e9 3c d1 79  d5 fb d1 e0 0f d2 44 e8  |q@E..<.y......D.|
00000180  7c 47 fe 7e f9 24 38 28  34 18 0c b5 b1 79 d5 90  ||G.~.$8(4....y..|
00000190  d5 22 98 ea d5 f6 8b d2  d7 9e 04 b5 95 e6 bc fb  |."..............|
000001a0  52 d3 6d 99 c8 bc a1 a3  bf cc 3d 94 10 6d 9b 2f  |R.m.......=..m./|
000001b0  5b b5 7c 8c 06 02 2c a4  f4 37 3c c9 c9 08 d9 d3  |[.|...,..7<.....|
000001c0  c5 6a 42 b1 6b 14 7b ca  34 30 16 90 0f 3a 84 6c  |.jB.k.{.40...:.l|
000001d0  c9 a6 9b 83 9c 4d b8 c5  3e a1 1c d8 84 0d b1 a0  |.....M..>.......|
000001e0  91 ad 6e 4f e2 50 c8 22  c3 31 5d b7 0c 90 13 99  |..nO.P.".1].....|
000001f0  ba f4 6b 8a 0d c5 eb 45  fb 7b 93 5e fb 26 4c a4  |..k....E.{.^.&L.|
00000200  2a 74 2c f6 cd bd 9f 2c  f5 9a 3d 52 00 fd 71 c4  |*t,....,..=R..q.|
00000210  a2 08 1c d9 0f 90 e2 c4  45 4e 75 67 7c db 18 29  |........ENug|..)|
00000220  f3 37 53 e5 3f 6f 79 72  10 44 c2 be be 54 bd f4  |.7S.?oyr.D...T..|
00000230  f9 de 6c 7d 78 fe cc 10  52 52 79 2b 11 41 e8 0d  |..l}x...RRy+.A..|
00000240  43 d7 97 61 f9 65 1f 47  5d 74 8c 63 72 2f 39 bc  |C..a.e.G]t.cr/9.|
00000250  e8 ad fd 2d 88 a3 96 46  11 dd 53 0b bb 1b e5 77  |...-...F..S....w|
00000260  77 a9 20 cd 0b 80 e4 ff  76 58 b7 3e db cd 07 02  |w. .....vX.>....|
00000270  e2 d2 2e f7 d2 fa 68 f7  59 7b aa 3b be 7a 48 33  |......h.Y{.;.zH3|
00000280  c8 1a e5 69 f6 a9 47 b1  27 0a cd ea 23 cd 4f ec  |...i..G.'...#.O.|
00000290  16 99 28 0a 39 a0 fa 68  6d e6 3b e7 4f eb 8b a2  |..(.9..hm.;.O...|
000002a0  71 ca a9 cb fe db 19 b1  72 86 5b b0 bf fb 66 d5  |q.......r.[...f.|
000002b0  0e e4 25 22 8e 01 40 ab  ed 67 76 a4 80 b2 b9 8f  |..%"..@..gv.....|
000002c0  2d 57 8c bf 48 9f 9c 59  74 9a 61 f0 66 0a 0e 72  |-W..H..Yt.a.f..r|
000002d0  32 ca cd ff 59 fb d5 22  c8 37 b4 56 03 02 eb 1a  |2...Y..".7.V....|
000002e0  e1 f7 fe a0 6b c5 69 3b  25 a5 41 f3 e5 c9 d7 45  |....k.i;%.A....E|
000002f0  9f 5c f1 ad 3a a4 e8 65  16 4c ae 8b 99 e2 d1 08  |.\..:..e.L......|
00000300  a3 ad 07 7e b2 cc e3 ba  76 74 28 04 1c 30 52 4f  |...~....vt(..0RO|
00000310  a3 16 74 65 78 a5 b2 ff  4b 91 be 3d 03 00 d0 f8  |..tex...K..=....|
00000320  92 ee 9a 0b ed 1f 42 04  d1 06 b1 26 6e b9 ca dc  |......B....&n...|
00000330  9f be 38 5e 95 66 89 cf  1c d6 3b 01 ca a5 17 43  |..8^.f....;....C|
00000340  28 39 32 bc 49 ef ce c8  c3 62 de bf b3 de af 86  |(92.I....b......|
00000350  24 5e 5c 8b 24 41 24 ae  07 e2 f9 65 1f 36 19 90  |$^\.$A$....e.6..|
00000360  f7 f6 6c 33 5f 33 df 4e  8a 70 80 a7 62 37 ef e8  |..l3_3.N.p..b7..|
00000370  02 17 b8 c3 5e ae b9 66  40 d2 98 a2 95 32 31 ac  |....^..f@....21.|
00000380  e5 06 ed 2c 21 e2 44 1c  f3 d0 45 17 84 e8 79 f8  |...,!.D...E...y.|
00000390  9c fb c5 d1 1e 5e 16 43  c7 56 3e ae 33 b8 6f 98  |.....^.C.V>.3.o.|
000003a0  42 2b 59 2a 9a 14 6c 4e  16 03 81 94 4f fa d0 d5  |B+Y*..lN....O...|
000003b0  58 9b 04 ed 66 0b 9e bd  1f 28 af cb 2a a5 fc bf  |X...f....(..*...|
000003c0  b5 f9 50 33 2e 16 70 c3  9b 71 8f fc ed 96 53 55  |..P3..p..q....SU|
000003d0  e5 14 7a 61 e1 e9 a9 93  dc 36 08 5b 52 ce 6d 61  |..za.....6.[R.ma|
000003e0  d9 23 cd 82 d9 7d 12 f4  57 20 09 77 08 53 61 50  |.#...}..W .w.SaP|
000003f0  da 51 b3 df f8 37 b8 da  f8 29 1b 32 90 ee d7 e0  |.Q...7...).2....|
00000400  b6 ee 54 af 33 12 25 bc  eb 69 d0 7c 76 a7 cb 48  |..T.3.%..i.|v..H|
00000410  44 19 b7 07 1a ac 30 32  58 56 92 e0 99 37 8b e6  |D.....02XV...7..|
00000420  c7 b4 ae dd bf a6 3c a8  33 d7 2b 35 83 32 32 03  |......<.3.+5.22.|
00000430  c8 99 4d 25 17 6b 36 1e  9c db 9d bb 53 aa 00 b0  |..M%.k6.....S...|
00000440  e7 d9 ee e0 f2 e3 44 a5  94 ca 52 fe 6b aa 72 db  |......D...R.k.r.|
00000450  d9 dc 99 ba a9 5f 6a 08  90 78 c6 3c a3 98 0c 9c  |....._j..x.<....|
00000460  7c 50 aa 71 aa 8f 1c 8c  39 30 9e 12 da 5f c3 8b  ||P.q....90..._..|
00000470  1f ab b8 ca 1f 32 30 2a  dc 29 9d 90 d4 57 c2 16  |.....20*.)...W..|
00000480  db ed 76 08 ed 9b 67 0a  18 9f 1a 18 6d 04 3e f4  |..v...g.....m.>.|
00000490  01 74 81 3d 6e 47 a7 0f  7c 55 56 e4 8f 0a dc c0  |.t.=nG..|UV.....|
000004a0  b6 d1 1c 11 a1 ce 6e 33  29 83 9c 51 ec d8 f2 db  |......n3)..Q....|
000004b0  e1 c8 14 b8 31 e2 b2 5d  cd 00 8a f3 79 4b 0b 7d  |....1..]....yK.}|
000004c0  69 a7 d7 4c 73 a7 1c f7  b0 4e e6 ff d2 db 73 6a  |i..Ls....N....sj|
000004d0  c0 65 a0 ef 8c 51 72 f3  ad de 2e 48 bd 86 40 36  |.e...Qr....H..@6|
000004e0  af 3a 66 78 66 1c 56 22  03 10 be 8d 9c 34 fa 3b  |.:fxf.V".....4.;|
000004f0  08 31 f0 69 9f 80 0e 4c  aa 73 fa c8 3f f8 4a ac  |.1.i...L.s..?.J.|
00000500  61 61 55 24 c1 71 70 d4  ab 48 3b e3 93 3e 15 f7  |aaU$.qp..H;..>..|
00000510  a7 21 8d cc cc c6 f6 c2  78 9f 75 e3 69 d3 3d 6d  |.!......x.u.i.=m|
00000520  2a c2 9a 22 8d 38 ab ba  99 91 6d 6f c0 73 33 4a  |*..".8....mo.s3J|
00000530  62 e1 a9 24 80 58 b3 45  25 e9 5a 70 43 64 e6 2e  |b..$.X.E%.ZpCd..|
00000540  ae 56 05 b2 32 0a 7f a3  c1 ae 08 99 0f 56 a7 53  |.V..2........V.S|
00000550  15 64 a3 df 0c f9 96 f8  c7 07 5f 42 b8 89 15 c2  |.d........_B....|
00000560  87 99 71 fe 74 45 1b 86  99 22 18 60 db f9 28 9e  |..q.tE...".`..(.|
00000570  fb 3d 90 73 5e 34 a9 ef  28 00 a5 2c af 7e a9 7a  |.=.s^4..(..,.~.z|
00000580  3f 70 79 eb bb e6 03 26  76 8c 05 75 13 1c 1d 5d  |?py....&v..u...]|
00000590  8f df 96 df b1 2e 3f 5a  49 1a b1 32 fc 09 af a5  |......?ZI..2....|
000005a0  54 4e 47 30 23 be eb 96  58 c3 34 9b 12 39 47 55  |TNG0#...X.4..9GU|
000005b0  d0 aa 15 b9 3a ac 4d 73  21 45 7e d8 ce 51 0a ff  |....:.Ms!E~..Q..|
000005c0  c2 14 53 68 ca 36 a6 68  29 67 4f ab 1f c4 9c 91  |..Sh.6.h)gO.....|
000005d0  4e fd 0e 23 0f ea d1 47  b9 33 0d 46 3d 6d 42 d1  |N..#...G.3.F=mB.|
000005e0  2c 24 29 8e dc 06 40 73  03 c8 b8 22 e3 e0 8c 80  |,$)...@s..."....|
000005f0  7d b4 06 b4 71 73 7a 83  cb 18 e9 dc a9 ac 5c 6f  |}...qsz.......\o|
00000600  3d 17 90 9b f6 de c0 f9  32 2a 77 62 87 85 ec cf  |=.......2*wb....|
00000610  69 ee bf 0e d6 83 ea d8  8b 31 00 7c be a0 cb 4a  |i........1.|...J|
00000620  d3 d2 7f 4b 9e e7 50 8b  46 ef 38 55 48 ba 87 14  |...K..P.F.8UH...|
00000630  d9 b3 a1 9d 5f e2 c5 51  86 f2 0d 03 55 91 7a 76  |...._..Q....U.zv|
00000640  23 20 20 b0 b3 03 c1 2e  ca b3 9e 70 33 03 5a cc  |#  ........p3.Z.|
00000650  fb 78 26 e9 8e cb c3 2c  d6 2e c9 5d d7 b1 69 64  |.x&....,...]..id|
00000660  0f 15 9c df ca 2a e5 d1  1c 8f ca a1 37 bb f2 d0  |.....*......7...|
00000670  e1 85 31 95 63 ef f8 71  a9 a3 75 97 72 b8 76 5a  |..1.c..q..u.r.vZ|
00000680  1d 7b 0c dc eb 7c 10 43  db 56 64 0b 1c 03 2f 76  |.{...|.C.Vd.../v|
00000690  0d 3c 62 0f 13 7f bc 48  4b c8 80 ac 63 db 01 9d  |.<b....HK...c...|
000006a0  d1 31 76 86 9c 5a 99 9f  62 21 70 e8 91 5c 28 ea  |.1v..Z..b!p..\(.|
000006b0  ef 3a 6e e7 27 cf 1f 68  40 09 cc 8b a0 c6 76 15  |.:n.'..h@.....v.|
000006c0  de 61 b0 b4 58 e7 af fe  de f2 9d 64 bb 46 8c ef  |.a..X......d.F..|
000006d0  eb a5 24 bd 15 b9 06 e7  d4 d5 a2 94 e5 74 8b 20  |..$..........t. |
000006e0  81 06 6e 65 20 e7 6a d8  fc b1 19 7f 26 74 30 6b  |..ne .j.....&t0k|
000006f0  15 6a c5 4a 98 26 be c2  aa 20 b0 98 4e da 8c a2  |.j.J.&... ..N...|
00000700  c4 aa af fa 81 e9 1b cf  03 cf 46 0e be 6f 63 03  |..........F..oc.|
00000710  66 30 41 4b 8f 91 0b ba  7b 86 f6 3f 99 ac e5 02  |f0AK....{..?....|
00000720  ce 61 87 7d 5c 6e 13 3f  5c ae b5 5e ed ec da e2  |.a.}\n.?\..^....|
00000730  89 97 0b c4 71 5a f8 83  1a c5 a7 cc a1 11 7d d3  |....qZ........}.|
00000740  15 e9 fe 0d 3a 56 cf 51  6c ad 3e 4d 0a 40 54 71  |....:V.Ql.>M.@Tq|
00000750  03 0a d5 00 ea 1d 68 32  cb f5 72 22 4e bc 48 78  |......h2..r"N.Hx|
00000760  c3 b1 af f8 d8 4c 83 ca  d4 d9 a2 29 26 00 d5 da  |.....L.....)&...|
00000770  c5 56 9d 19 16 e6 36 bf  61 f9 21 77 ca 4a 9f 85  |.V....6.a.!w.J..|
00000780  c8 be cc c3 a6 b0 bc 7e  1e 6a f2 fc d4 29 86 38  |.......~.j...).8|
00000790  bb a1 eb a0 21 0a 2f 73  5d af 45 4f d3 01 05 28  |....!./s].EO...(|
000007a0  9c 8c 8c f0 d0 be bc 75  8d 4f d2 14 ad 9d 49 22  |.......u.O....I"|
000007b0  9a ff f4 92 c1 b9 01 77  07 fc f2 8b d9 ff 4f 9b  |.......w......O.|
000007c0  a7 52 e7 4d 37 79 ac bc  5e af 1e 42 9a 84 a2 d6  |.R.M7y..^..B....|
000007d0  d4 14 cc eb 80 e2 0e 04  4e 13 f6 d0 da 06 26 94  |........N.....&.|
000007e0  c7 03 4b f4 37 2c a2 20  ff ce 1d 54 ee 65 a7 7f  |..K.7,. ...T.e..|
000007f0  a7 e9 43 fe 69 ca c2 17  2d cf 23 95 6f 0b 63 db  |..C.i...-.#.o.c.|
00000800  ff 39 17 5b 2c 34 66 62  c8 6b f1 74 48 ec 74 4c  |.9.[,4fb.k.tH.tL|
00000810  a1 2e 4d 9c f3 b2 64 4b  d5 0f 59 89 a3 e3 7f bd  |..M...dK..Y.....|
00000820  55 1f 8a e1 91 97 7c df  a4 86 7b 45 df 54 a1 3c  |U.....|...{E.T.<|
00000830  0f e9 9f 87 f4 76 8b 15  bb 18 a8 ff 56 38 ff bc  |.....v......V8..|
00000840  8b ae 60 7d 71 65 25 83  9d 84 49 03 39 de 89 6c  |..`}qe%...I.9..l|
00000850  f7 dd e2 ef a0 3f 82 78  12 2b cb f1 c1 0d 7e a6  |.....?.x.+....~.|
00000860  eb 46 22 7e 4e a9 ef 58  34 03 9b 7a 4a 0c d3 0e  |.F"~N..X4..zJ...|
00000870  0a 89 21 ef 55 36 ba 28  9d 8a 23 d0 d1 8b 81 46  |..!.U6.(..#....F|
00000880  ba 41 f5 49 43 6a df 7b  a8 21 31 a9 44 8c 6a af  |.A.ICj.{.!1.D.j.|
00000890  da 57 fc e7 9a 24 3b 85  64 d3 9e b2 c1 ba 4d fd  |.W...$;.d.....M.|
000008a0  69 8d cc 20 b7 9f 50 50  9d 34 68 b1 59 2e 70 5c  |i.. ..PP.4h.Y.p\|
000008b0  f8 bd fc 0d 14 63 91 e3  62 36 a2 26 20 62 c9 0e  |.....c..b6.& b..|
000008c0  5a b0 0f c3 6d 30 6a 89  a8 4e 36 b5 30 1e eb 5f  |Z...m0j..N6.0.._|
000008d0  80 6a ba eb a3 a7 70 51  b8 8e cb 72 df 13 8f 7f  |.j....pQ...r....|
000008e0  86 28 41 db 6b e8 03 8c  ae 7a b9 72 ef 56 4c 24  |.(A.k....z.r.VL$|
000008f0  f5 c6 77 53 8c 49 f2 38  20 7a 4d 5e a9 38 ee 81  |..wS.I.8 zM^.8..|
00000900  5a 0a 72 e0 83 2a e0 33  b6 1f ac 57 59 6e 41 1d  |Z.r..*.3...WYnA.|
00000910  35 2b 1d e0 4b 9f dd b5  ad c6 7f 75 ef ed 4d 8e  |5+..K......u..M.|
00000920  36 ce 90 ab b2 7e 5f 2b  83 00 59 4a 14 84 c6 14  |6....~_+..YJ....|
00000930  81 09 90 82 92 8b 99 4a  ae c4 41 85 52 3c 75 49  |.......J..A.R<uI|
00000940  75 fc 7b a2 ab 69 b3 65  90 5c 94 a2 8f f4 b1 93  |u.{..i.e.\......|
00000950  ec df f7 e0 82 63 b0 9f  4f f0 86 9e 4b 4e 89 84  |.....c..O...KN..|
00000960  b3 05 74 09 2b 1c ca 74  4c 9f cf 65 97 ab c2 6c  |..t.+..tL..e...l|
00000970  ce ca 27 03 7d d5 09 ee  e2 f8 61 56 06 ff 56 09  |..'.}.....aV..V.|
00000980  d9 e5 83 ee 8d 76 c5 7c  88 c5 b2 5a ff 1d 79 e5  |.....v.|...Z..y.|
00000990  40 a9 8c c4 3a ad e0 5c  e5 19 48 3f 8e 27 9e 3e  |@...:..\..H?.'.>|
000009a0  cd e8 dc a7 2a e5 c5 9d  98 e2 02 7a 88 31 0c 5a  |....*......z.1.Z|
000009b0  30 9f 89 89 58 08 11 62  90 b4 38 68 c1 16 9a bf  |0...X..b..8h....|
000009c0  4d 6f 60 0c fd 70 73 51  b6 e6 46 55 25 47 b8 8f  |Mo`..psQ..FU%G..|
000009d0  47 8b bd 5b 10 d1 da 86  13 5b fc ee a0 9d d5 2b  |G..[.....[.....+|
000009e0  f9 53 ce e4 e8 cc a0 82  7a e0 cd 7c f8 34 aa 0c  |.S......z..|.4..|
000009f0  30 89 37 8a 75 15 54 5e  6a 78 1e 82 e9 af e5 3a  |0.7.u.T^jx.....:|
00000a00  46 05 90 a0 87 e7 cf bc  eb 6b 28 e2 02 13 85 23  |F........k(....#|
00000a10  1a c5 c0 43 ee 06 b9 1d  4e 09 86 48 18 bf cd 32  |...C....N..H...2|
00000a20  bc ee 0f 2d fe 5c 07 e6  0f c2 1b a8 08 d3 2a 41  |...-.\........*A|
00000a30  97 be d1 f9 e1 60 d6 bd  1d a6 46 2e ea 9c 79 3a  |.....`....F...y:|
00000a40  2d 54 8c 06 54 70 a0 35  54 63 cd aa b5 f5 99 2c  |-T..Tp.5Tc.....,|
00000a50  d9 ed 1b 3b 48 8a 21 bb  17 8a f7 89 3d ac f3 34  |...;H.!.....=..4|
00000a60  85 9f 5c 26 74 87 64 30  39 91 c7 18 ce cb b1 bf  |..\&t.d09.......|
00000a70  dd 81 b9 f2 12 98 24 40  1d 7e 8f 30 9f 87 d6 62  |......$@.~.0...b|
00000a80  b4 02 66 42 83 e5 1e 76  67 72 99 5c d3 87 2e b4  |..fB...vgr.\....|
00000a90  e8 00 8c 94 12 5f 51 89  52 98 db 9d 13 71 5b 12  |....._Q.R....q[.|
00000aa0  3f b9 bf f5 9d 57 ba 12  02 cb 18 b8 5b 6e a5 de  |?....W......[n..|
00000ab0  41 99 b4 71 62 58 65 3f  1a 43 83 f1 75 75 63 65  |A..qbXe?.C..uuce|
00000ac0  5c f3 e1 37 d2 b2 13 3d  dc 96 97 4f ad 21 5b 81  |\..7...=...O.![.|
00000ad0  a2 b7 59 5f 00 09 55 ff  10 8a 75 87 ea 54 07 4d  |..Y_..U...u..T.M|
00000ae0  9d ff b4 bd da c7 e4 43  dc 6b 41 cc 0d 64 3e 92  |.......C.kA..d>.|
00000af0  24 10 73 ce 0b a0 d7 d9  f6 c5 5d 4b 7a 40 51 ce  |$.s.......]Kz@Q.|
00000b00  c5 38 46 cd 88 06 03 eb  5e f1 43 24 16 31 3e ce  |.8F.....^.C$.1>.|
00000b10  18 02 d5 b7 99 33 b2 57  78 79 6d 2d 21 aa 22 68  |.....3.Wxym-!."h|
00000b20  bf b9 b9 1a 3c 9d a3 0f  9e b0 7d 2d 85 60 ba 29  |....<.....}-.`.)|
00000b30  f7 e0 91 11 ec 21 bd e0  bd 37 21 78 1b 50 f2 24  |.....!...7!x.P.$|
00000b40  c1 1e 8a 75 90 14 c6 4b  22 85 94 25 b0 1a 13 ee  |...u...K"..%....|
00000b50  88 1d 40 3e 08 05 ef 13  c0 92 e3 44 c9 ca 8b 6c  |..@>.......D...l|
00000b60  ae dc ca 03 eb 27 01 6a  32 ed d0 bd 9d dc d0 fd  |.....'.j2.......|
00000b70  62 03 70 1c 73 90 e5 9c  89 d8 f4 83 88 8c 8d 36  |b.p.s..........6|
00000b80  b7 d8 13 64 54 61 a1 f3  27 af d9 61 f7 92 ba 55  |...dTa..'..a...U|
00000b90  37 36 24 4c a3 ca 45 ae  45 08 31 f5 61 ae f6 ef  |76$L..E.E.1.a...|
00000ba0  fb 2e 53 2d 93 f6 8f 45  35 36 ef cf 48 7e 68 7c  |..S-...E56..H~h||
00000bb0  8a 18 ee 80 fb 36 c0 11  f7 84 0a f1 96 4c ec 88  |.....6.......L..|
00000bc0  3f 8c bc f5 e3 9b 6c 2b  56 c9 6f 87 51 b2 c5 ac  |?.....l+V.o.Q...|
00000bd0  65 0f 42 bb 40 98 ed 91  3f c2 42 a9 c6 91 6b 75  |e.B.@...?.B...ku|
00000be0  55 5b 1b f1 75 ea e8 f9  a9 a5 90 8a 43 aa fd f3  |U[..u.......C...|
00000bf0  78 89 19 30 8f 12 ca 61  5c 32 77 91 93 37 42 02  |x..0...a\2w..7B.|
00000c00  b3 77 d8 6c d7 38 02 6a  53 f9 3b a7 03 25 f4 66  |.w.l.8.jS.;..%.f|
00000c10  67 94 0b 2c 09 92 5b 89  50 5a 4e 70 39 23 e1 97  |g..,..[.PZNp9#..|
00000c20  98 a9 5b 6c 1c b8 bd e6  8d e6 c2 6d 5e b9 49 e8  |..[l.......m^.I.|
00000c30  c7 3c 54 cd 81 4a c1 4b  75 26 84 7f 53 bd 42 66  |.<T..J.Ku&..S.Bf|
00000c40  96 54 b9 df d8 a2 7b 18  a5 ca d7 29 15 9c b9 99  |.T....{....)....|
00000c50  3e 1d 9b c7 9e c2 87 b9  ce 05 bd ec 63 3a d6 7f  |>...........c:..|
00000c60  5e 5a ca f7 09 4f b6 03  14 6c a0 0c 4b 90 b3 dd  |^Z...O...l..K...|
00000c70  df 96 8b 1c 82 5e 64 f3  c5 9c 30 d8 0f e1 e2 ca  |.....^d...0.....|
00000c80  4c 62 3e ce 7d e6 ed 2d  cd d4 5d 26 7c ae 3a 96  |Lb>.}..-..]&|.:.|
00000c90  f0 df c0 cf 8b 92 4a ce  09 fc 70 06 b8 ff 02 df  |......J...p.....|
00000ca0  97 c7 73 b6 4a cd 79 c9  b7 52 bb 2b 55 3e a4 c2  |..s.J.y..R.+U>..|
00000cb0  15 5b b1 5b 94 fe 90 9e  46 4e c5 59 35 fe 00 4b  |.[.[....FN.Y5..K|
00000cc0  5a 1e 88 ea 79 9a c1 93  5d 6d 69 ff 29 79 d3 8b  |Z...y...]mi.)y..|
00000cd0  53 84 43 01 41 48 b2 a0  ad df e8 d9 29 1c 5b 21  |S.C.AH......).[!|
00000ce0  9c 3f 74 6e 60 7b b9 bc  ef 7a 69 8c 4a 00 9c 89  |.?tn`{...zi.J...|
00000cf0  ae 5f 82 c1 31 17 57 2a  26 79 a7 e2 8f f8 e1 aa  |._..1.W*&y......|
00000d00  c7 3c 6f 20 9e 24 20 0d  da 93 c3 70 80 94 f7 60  |.<o .$ ....p...`|
00000d10  af 99 9f c1 46 d7 fa 34  31 98 08 70 6f 14 e3 87  |....F..41..po...|
00000d20  cd 59 0e 0d 71 26 a7 11  7f f4 08 fd 69 64 be af  |.Y..q&......id..|
00000d30  dc e3 da 51 b2 7e 1e af  a0 d3 3a 90 d5 26 cf 52  |...Q.~....:..&.R|
00000d40  87 91 7c b1 1c 13 e1 24  e6 4d 11 f9 ae 78 93 ee  |..|....$.M...x..|
00000d50  c0 de a5 ae f9 f4 cf 33  88 aa 69 b7 c7 25 a8 08  |.......3..i..%..|
00000d60  64 61 16 b2 86 70 25 56  97 df 91 98 48 54 9b ba  |da...p%V....HT..|
00000d70  f8 f1 35 d9 f1 c7 40 6e  a3 00 67 9d bf 79 58 8d  |..5...@n..g..yX.|
00000d80  88 19 e6 6a 24 c1 f1 38  5d 72 47 20 d4 a1 74 2d  |...j$..8]rG ..t-|
00000d90  7d 42 4d 9f c5 c9 8b e3  1e f9 b0 b7 dc c1 ad 4e  |}BM............N|
00000da0  6d 21 90 80 e1 d0 88 5b  e9 43 03 20 2d 29 4c 8e  |m!.....[.C. -)L.|
00000db0  36 a7 a7 a4 41 9e 5d da  af 02 a7 a5 88 6b 70 9d  |6...A.]......kp.|
00000dc0  11 99 f7 3e 86 52 32 e0  2d da 35 81 75 f6 a8 ac  |...>.R2.-.5.u...|
00000dd0  70 b2 99 3c ee cd 99 d7  d4 10 7e 98 b7 17 2b 74  |p..<......~...+t|
00000de0  76 d0 e9 ac c8 a2 a7 d3  09 71 42 ee 23 18 b2 4b  |v........qB.#..K|
00000df0  d2 c0 5b b0 67 8b 9f 08  d9 a9 85 24 f3 56 c9 d5  |..[.g......$.V..|
00000e00  73 12 f7 b7 91 87 d2 98  d0 79 bd 82 0d 4c 63 b8  |s........y...Lc.|
00000e10  4f d2 3d f5 37 92 04 6c  05 14 7e c9 f7 da 62 2c  |O.=.7..l..~...b,|
00000e20  f9 a1 53 9b 0b 8e 9d 21  2b 32 47 83 6a 24 a6 e4  |..S....!+2G.j$..|
00000e30  62 bb 73 a1 66 1d ba b4  30 de 87 b4 d7 e0 46 6e  |b.s.f...0.....Fn|
00000e40  03 62 6d 12 bc 42 ea 1c  b6 2f 84 5d 2d a4 08 6a  |.bm..B.../.]-..j|
00000e50  22 f5 2b bc 98 38 09 37  df 08 3e 66 b6 47 b6 38  |".+..8.7..>f.G.8|
00000e60  02 ac c1 3d 92 f0 93 8a  ec d5 a0 42 fe be 23 22  |...=.......B..#"|
00000e70  9a 6c 3a dc 0e 8d 84 16  6d 4f ac cf 50 51 53 99  |.l:.....mO..PQS.|
00000e80  84 6b c8 a6 fa 5b 3b cb  10 fd be 92 1b 47 e2 88  |.k...[;......G..|
00000e90  93 91 a4 34 ce ed fd eb  08 e2 16 ad ce c8 ce 80  |...4............|
00000ea0  23 61 9a 99 1c 47 0f 2c  f8 d5 25 8e e4 b4 d6 5a  |#a...G.,..%....Z|
00000eb0  a5 25 0e 55 c0 e6 8b d5  07 ab f9 5c 19 05 05 62  |.%.U.......\...b|
00000ec0  cd 9c 78 e0 97 4e 6c d1  4e 6e 3a 5f 81 4b f1 a8  |..x..Nl.Nn:_.K..|
00000ed0  73 6c c3 65 9a 2b e6 5f  3a 4b e2 9d 01 18 56 0e  |sl.e.+._:K....V.|
00000ee0  09 e1 2e 04 e7 e7 32 62  13 34 fd d9 a0 25 58 c4  |......2b.4...%X.|
00000ef0  f3 55 df 82 1f c0 fb 6b  d3 8a be 20 2b e1 38 ec  |.U.....k... +.8.|
00000f00  b3 48 fa 80 c0 0a 7c 6b  8a f6 16 4b 1e ea 6b 4d  |.H....|k...K..kM|
00000f10  26 d1 c3 4e e4 88 b6 fe  c0 54 eb 52 36 a6 4a 89  |&..N.....T.R6.J.|
00000f20  20 19 e2 ce 22 20 8c 59  8a ed 37 69 e9 33 f6 ee  | ..." .Y..7i.3..|
00000f30  b8 a2 ae 86 66 72 7c 90  48 d4 78 7c b4 8a 78 29  |....fr|.H.x|..x)|
00000f40  27 23 39 6e 5b f6 b3 74  77 80 14 76 99 93 b2 e9  |'#9n[..tw..v....|
00000f50  0e ac 23 2c 6f 66 2a 7c  60 a6 d1 b7 65 19 73 c4  |..#,of*|`...e.s.|
00000f60  d9 db ab 43 51 cf 82 82  2e e1 65 ed b4 90 cd 78  |...CQ.....e....x|
00000f70  91 82 e6 42 87 c1 d9 71  36 eb bd 15 30 09 c5 e7  |...B...q6...0...|
00000f80  bb ab 09 2b ba 41 e4 3b  df d6 d9 dd b8 20 58 83  |...+.A.;..... X.|
00000f90  f0 b5 d1 fb 28 95 35 04  f2 cf b5 d1 96 22 9d d8  |....(.5......"..|
00000fa0  35 22 73 5f d3 dc 7e e8  a9 5e a0 1b c4 fb 03 a2  |5"s_..~..^......|
00000fb0  21 54 a4 ae 97 bc 17 52  62 76 de db 1e d4 d5 41  |!T.....Rbv.....A|
00000fc0  4b a8 29 ea 10 bd 88 49  e9 4a b3 10 87 19 df 1b  |K.)....I.J......|
00000fd0  d0 23 c9 1b ba 43 7c 27  8d 59 3a 02 58 7c 8e 96  |.#...C|'.Y:.X|..|
00000fe0  34 7c a7 e5 57 0b a5 4c  f7 1c 2a 12 da 4f ef f4  |4|..W..L..*..O..|
00000ff0  47 13 8b 63 fb ad 97 55  ca 40 d7 37 59 f7 9d d6  |G..c...U.@.7Y...|
00001000  2c c8 d1 76 2c e0 96 a7  20 e4 9d f8 99 16 f8 bf  |,..v,... .......|
00001010  9f c1 95 fa dd 0d a3 bb  b8 b5 ab 1c 25 0d e4 f5  |............%...|
00001020  47 9c 85 4b 1f d1 49 30  bd 52 7b 12 be af 1a 89  |G..K..I0.R{.....|
00001030  5b dd 97 50 fc 16 bb 2c  c7 7d db 25 9a 01 15 bb  |[..P...,.}.%....|
00001040  de 2f 47 26 31 b1 f6 3e  d0 a6 ff de 86 33 df 3f  |./G&1..>.....3.?|
00001050  05 a6 ed 6d ad 9f 6b 9b  0c 9f a1 72 62 b8 82 74  |...m..k....rb..t|
00001060  b5 bd e0 ed 2c e1 be 7f  01 a7 aa 4f 03 cf 63 7b  |....,......O..c{|
00001070  9b 97 eb 38 6e c3 da 86  17 87 6e 29 55 8f c3 61  |...8n.....n)U..a|
00001080  1a e8 92 96 98 bb 05 43  69 77 b2 f5 81 98 00 6e  |.......Ciw.....n|
00001090  35 1d d5 ae 9e 33 9f c2  78 cd 05 39 aa 90 2a ce  |5....3..x..9..*.|
000010a0  87 9e b4 bf a6 92 85 3d  40 b7 59 fe a2 51 61 9a  |.......=@.Y..Qa.|
000010b0  d0 14 b2 6c 4b dd 66 03  8b 7a fd 83 c5 dc 30 95  |...lK.f..z....0.|
000010c0  23 7a 79 01 ea c4 81 7f  82 ff 14 56 a1 18 20 6e  |#zy........V.. n|
000010d0  69 00 85 cf a4 c8 b5 62  6e 7b 47 ca f0 75 22 8d  |i......bn{G..u".|
000010e0  8e f6 bd 08 60 a9 7d 9b  7f 54 87 28 db a1 70 13  |....`.}..T.(..p.|
000010f0  fc 58 e3 af 7c 83 4c f7  dc 9c e5 28 4c a5 5a da  |.X..|.L....(L.Z.|
00001100  f1 ca 4e 17 9b 5e 29 e1  57 64 ac 94 73 b5 52 bd  |..N..^).Wd..s.R.|
00001110  52 ee 34 c8 37 1c 0c 27  f5 13 98 c8 54 68 54 d0  |R.4.7..'....ThT.|
00001120  00 3b fe e0 dd f2 26 00  40 92 ce 09 ff 82 cd f6  |.;....&.@.......|
00001130  02 b8 55 72 3b 8f 94 d2  59 b5 3f af e5 8c 6d 6b  |..Ur;...Y.?...mk|
00001140  21 97 12 d0 82 ff 32 3f  f7 89 ad 7f 0a 5a 52 91  |!.....2?.....ZR.|
00001150  98 8a ce ba 6c 60 e2 fe  df 79 76 06 55 f1 4d ad  |....l`...yv.U.M.|
00001160  df 9f 01 86 22 17 f1 56  51 da 99 52 52 fb a9 09  |...."..VQ..RR...|
00001170  26 ad 4c ff 85 8c 4b c7  a5 e7 55 62 9f 95 e6 58  |&.L...K...Ub...X|
00001180  64 87 35 40 2c 1d 24 23  a2 fb a9 b0 1d c3 e8 ad  |d.5@,.$#........|
00001190  cd 46 93 6e b8 98 fd cd  a4 68 41 59 19 26 dd cf  |.F.n.....hAY.&..|
000011a0  25 75 b1 72 79 19 b7 44  c9 f2 27 eb 24 ea 32 94  |%u.ry..D..'.$.2.|
000011b0  8a 94 87 a6 3d ec 29 b9  8f ab 0e 9d 7a 51 fa e3  |....=.).....zQ..|
000011c0  2b 6e 9f 48 ab 82 2a d7  9f 4d ab b8 3e 6e 3a 24  |+n.H..*..M..>n:$|
000011d0  85 b2 b5 59 1c c3 87 c3  5a e2 43 5d 9f 00 2c 39  |...Y....Z.C]..,9|
000011e0  07 7b eb 8c 3e ac 51 13  a3 9f 27 88 e4 7d c7 a2  |.{..>.Q...'..}..|
000011f0  b8 21 77 09 c5 39 f0 a7  b1 cb 37 d9 25 a9 70 ac  |.!w..9....7.%.p.|
00001200  83 ac f2 10 14 61 18 66  c1 d1 eb 9c a2 b6 48 a8  |.....a.f......H.|
00001210  30 8e 19 35 dc da d3 4a  2b 60 e5 d6 42 c2 4b 53  |0..5...J+`..B.KS|
00001220  ab b8 99 fc 92 34 92 66  d2 80 75 26 4a d2 91 5e  |.....4.f..u&J..^|
00001230  e1 41 28 83 33 93 68 c8  0c fd 5f c8 41 d5 aa 6e  |.A(.3.h..._.A..n|
00001240  e3 f7 4a 3e 62 6e 25 d4  19 55 6a 5e c3 fe e6 e0  |..J>bn%..Uj^....|
00001250  25 52 13 1b 83 54 a5 9b  32 77 72 1c 3c ca f6 3f  |%R...T..2wr.<..?|
00001260  b0 4d 70 a6 cb 23 60 54  62 58 12 ce da 14 8b f0  |.Mp..#`TbX......|
00001270  0b 78 c1 0c d2 21 a6 97  7f 68 a5 3b 9d 57 7c ab  |.x...!...h.;.W|.|
00001280  fa ab 82 e4 1e ad b0 d2  4f 2b 8b fc a5 a8 10 93  |........O+......|
00001290  d9 58 af 2c 4b 2a 4f 15  59 37 50 7e f3 a5 63 7e  |.X.,K*O.Y7P~..c~|
000012a0  64 46 82 62 b2 91 6a e7  41 ad 61 e7 2d 21 66 a5  |dF.b..j.A.a.-!f.|
000012b0  f6 d1 83 9d 16 ec 57 3b  5f 24 be a9 0a 7c 9a 9f  |......W;_$...|..|
000012c0  71 8f 52 fc cc 09 5b 04  6d e3 88 34 21 d0 55 98  |q.R...[.m..4!.U.|
000012d0  38 63 fe 3a 61 de 5c f4  26 eb ce e3 5c b9 e9 46  |8c.:a.\.&...\..F|
000012e0  5e 7c 0b 64 86 af ee 6e  f5 be 18 8e fe 2e 14 2e  |^|.d...n........|
000012f0  42 2b 1b 38 ea 00 b6 5e  9b cf a9 e7 1a dc d0 83  |B+.8...^........|
00001300  a5 1c 9b 4c c5 44 a3 69  c2 ca 79 81 da 4e 05 38  |...L.D.i..y..N.8|
00001310  14 cb a9 c5 15 75 5c f3  4c 6e 4c 97 d3 ce 02 71  |.....u\.LnL....q|
00001320  2a 6c 75 e2 92 34 93 85  2a 5a af 14 72 25 a7 de  |*lu..4..*Z..r%..|
00001330  d7 b7 c6 d4 0a 60 25 4a  ae f3 43 43 d7 bd 38 fc  |.....`%J..CC..8.|
00001340  04 cc 95 c9 9e bd 25 de  04 19 c6 23 7b c0 8b 41  |......%....#{..A|
00001350  53 e1 b4 8d 4b 87 2e 97  3d d2 74 ca e9 8e 33 4f  |S...K...=.t...3O|
00001360  d2 81 d5 e0 f7 bd 03 66  ee 76 fc 71 05 bf c6 f1  |.......f.v.q....|
00001370  52 0c bd cb e8 44 af fe  a0 2e 0d 6e 31 33 7f c0  |R....D.....n13..|
00001380  18 c7 dc f0 c8 8a 9f b4  0f ce f1 28 fe 43 23 d2  |...........(.C#.|
00001390  84 44 3a c7 d9 47 33 27  04 ae ef cc b4 da 08 c9  |.D:..G3'........|
000013a0  48 71 17 48 ca ba 2b 36  4b 78 74 92 33 5b e5 a5  |Hq.H..+6Kxt.3[..|
000013b0  de e8 5e 48 88 30 b4 1c  c3 3b 1d 88 db db 6c fa  |..^H.0...;....l.|
000013c0  45 9f b8 38 87 b6 dc 5e  a3 1d ec dc 60 d1 de d5  |E..8...^....`...|
000013d0  80 88 14 b1 ad 4e c6 2f  73 e6 17 d0 a0 fa 3b 17  |.....N./s.....;.|
000013e0  64 15 74 71 41 34 76 b7  ea 87 14 72 e6 1a 0f 30  |d.tqA4v....r...0|
000013f0  b0 56 cb 6b 4a e6 51 12  77 b3 5d 5e 1b 9a 84 35  |.V.kJ.Q.w.]^...5|
00001400  3b 0d 3a ac e1 ea 36 8d  8f 2a 11 45 6a 70 9c 66  |;.:...6..*.Ejp.f|
00001410  98 ee 0e e2 31 34 2c 02  b2 fc 13 5d 6e 7c f6 08  |....14,....]n|..|
00001420  cc 7a 99 75 66 e8 3e fa  6a 74 47 cb 9c 46 4a f5  |.z.uf.>.jtG..FJ.|
00001430  46 1b 2d 4a 8d 3d 3c 04  ff 6c 64 d2 9b 82 b6 0a  |F.-J.=<..ld.....|
00001440  b5 e3 97 cb 50 5f 39 9e  c9 98 b1 66 7c 56 2b e3  |....P_9....f|V+.|
00001450  4d 03 68 2e 69 af 78 b9  0d a5 96 80 74 22 c4 65  |M.h.i.x.....t".e|
00001460  e1 38 04 75 c0 cc a3 bb  57 12 90 34 c2 a6 3f 1a  |.8.u....W..4..?.|
00001470  95 aa b0 45 f5 57 78 36  10 05 9e 8d 77 4a fb 57  |...E.Wx6....wJ.W|
00001480  c4 d2 ab 3c 1c 36 81 f3  fa bc 34 66 c4 cb e2 a3  |...<.6....4f....|
00001490  bc f5 39 a4 75 db d1 02  08 e4 df d3 23 d1 63 4c  |..9.u.......#.cL|
000014a0  4b 21 08 85 f3 12 b3 2f  fc 0a f5 14 6a b3 b1 4e  |K!...../....j..N|
000014b0  4d 44 85 47 f9 4d 3b 94  25 2f d6 66 9e 39 6b 80  |MD.G.M;.%/.f.9k.|
000014c0  95 9a f4 b7 10 00 e2 c9  30 9a 34 2f d2 04 c4 30  |........0.4/...0|
000014d0  b7 e2 b8 a2 af 01 83 89  5a 28 55 ed 9a f2 65 79  |........Z(U...ey|
000014e0  61 2a 86 1e 93 ed 50 56  b1 46 aa 5b 6e 05 1d 54  |a*....PV.F.[n..T|
000014f0  19 5b 92 50 42 6f 1b 11  3b a2 32 36 72 b0 a6 9f  |.[.PBo..;.26r...|
00001500  a3 5f b4 a6 d7 ad ff d5  73 52 64 d3 fa be 68 24  |._......sRd...h$|
00001510  c2 5b 2f 2d 98 cb 85 09  16 61 c7 ce dc 9c 59 ef  |.[/-.....a....Y.|
00001520  3c 34 70 9e e7 71 fc 41  c6 6a e0 6b 96 bd 10 79  |<4p..q.A.j.k...y|
00001530  90 14 51 50 7a 64 56 ae  14 1d a6 66 f4 58 f8 a1  |..QPzdV....f.X..|
00001540  4d 1d c0 3a 4f d5 20 90  6e a3 5b 83 4d 52 b2 14  |M..:O. .n.[.MR..|
00001550  2a ce 63 54 7e 32 d0 6d  04 85 bb b3 67 74 3c fa  |*.cT~2.m....gt<.|
00001560  ad 8f 47 a4 0d e1 45 01  a2 10 63 9f 0d 5a 81 63  |..G...E...c..Z.c|
00001570  0e c7 45 fa 32 3a 32 a8  48 6b ad 37 07 66 b6 1c  |..E.2:2.Hk.7.f..|
00001580  8d 7b 2e 5e 76 98 a1 5c  84 e3 9a d6 a3 15 f9 2e  |.{.^v..\........|
00001590  0f b3 15 a7 43 af 10 8c  72 ac 92 7a b5 9b 47 1a  |....C...r..z..G.|
000015a0  22 2b 06 1b 08 bd b7 d6  fe 1e c9 20 2c 4f 72 4d  |"+......... ,OrM|
000015b0  57 6e 7c 2a 05 84 89 33  f9 80 cf a3 5e ca 63 1f  |Wn|*...3....^.c.|
000015c0  1a 67 ee c8 1e 20 c1 00  e4 95 97 d1 c9 13 a5 58  |.g... .........X|
000015d0  f9 43 97 86 44 d2 a0 1b  f6 8f 54 27 2a b2 bb f3  |.C..D.....T'*...|
000015e0  09 33 19 66 e7 c1 48 f9  88 ba 75 af 64 ce 53 40  |.3.f..H...u.d.S@|
000015f0  c0 31 d1 72 39 bb 08 4d  12 5a 7e 93 74 09 48 1b  |.1.r9..M.Z~.t.H.|
00001600  79 83 ba 8d b2 03 a4 23  6f 19 e0 7a f2 a5 55 48  |y......#o..z..UH|
00001610  b3 2f fd e8 59 74 ad bf  99 ca 23 f9 9c e7 e2 8e  |./..Yt....#.....|
00001620  db 70 05 d8 33 cd dc 78  fa a9 b6 3f 97 16 d2 88  |.p..3..x...?....|
00001630  2f e3 b6 bf d0 d8 1f 28  fe 8f bd 45 d6 cc 3a 6e  |/......(...E..:n|
00001640  c6 85 a0 90 b1 73 12 bf  42 33 bd 23 4f b7 fc 5f  |.....s..B3.#O.._|
00001650  8e 5c 4d 32 4b 6a 07 09  f3 9b 83 36 b1 7d ba 71  |.\M2Kj.....6.}.q|
00001660  d9 28 00 0e f4 37 df 45  76 b5 c3 fe ea 42 7d 1e  |.(...7.Ev....B}.|
00001670  a3 3a ed 90 00 af 0e 27  6c b7 25 29 ac 16 57 9b  |.:.....'l.%)..W.|
00001680  73 4b 66 8e 8d d9 40 d2  44 d6 7f bd 85 c8 6d 12  |sKf...@.D.....m.|
00001690  d1 ce dd ad 34 2f 8c e3  9e e2 0e 4c 0f 43 79 ae  |....4/.....L.Cy.|
000016a0  0d 6e 72 ee 61 da c7 94  b5 0a f9 eb 55 2a 9b 56  |.nr.a.......U*.V|
000016b0  82 9e 52 13 74 59 1e 45  dd 55 03 18 5d 49 7c 1c  |..R.tY.E.U..]I|.|
000016c0  1e 5b ca 4f 24 4f 0d 7f  47 61 b3 27 bc 77 0e 62  |.[.O$O..Ga.'.w.b|
000016d0  aa 72 e3 93 e3 4a f3 4c  8c ad 81 99 d7 c7 20 1c  |.r...J.L...... .|
000016e0  ce f8 76 d4 05 63 6a 2b  ea 69 a1 cd 60 85 84 33  |..v..cj+.i..`..3|
000016f0  ce 08 69 a0 e8 8d 9c 2a  17 cb f0 3e 32 40 81 f7  |..i....*...>2@..|
00001700  35 91 ce 11 c0 b3 ab 85  96 21 c3 1f 83 b6 d1 8a  |5........!......|
00001710  ec 60 46 89 90 8a 98 f9  3d 90 ed 17 a3 ab 24 33  |.`F.....=.....$3|
00001720  2b 14 9f 93 27 a6 d0 0c  03 a0 22 12 4e 4d 14 ba  |+...'.....".NM..|
00001730  12 10 a0 8c c3 52 a5 47  b1 ff 97 b9 a5 46 bc 71  |.....R.G.....F.q|
00001740  d6 b5 21 4b 71 11 76 05  59 77 b1 7d 09 fd 80 8f  |..!Kq.v.Yw.}....|
00001750  62 c6 b2 2c 12 36 27 a2  60 61 34 ff 5c 02 15 ce  |b..,.6'.`a4.\...|
00001760  b1 41 d6 e7 ff cd d7 7d  c7 f6 1e c7 f3 09 32 a7  |.A.....}......2.|
00001770  fb 86 29 bc ba 8b ff 09  65 4b 75 0e ef de f2 60  |..).....eKu....`|
00001780  29 a5 8b 81 4f 8a c7 14  71 47 77 1d 2f ef 7d 73  |)...O...qGw./.}s|
00001790  3f 2d 4d 41 c0 54 9f f5  11 7a 93 89 96 f1 b0 4b  |?-MA.T...z.....K|
000017a0  08 b1 e3 c5 11 1e ad 8b  79 ef 39 25 cc 5a 5c c1  |........y.9%.Z\.|
000017b0  ab 0d 19 42 65 05 32 75  4e 50 d6 79 32 ca 8d 19  |...Be.2uNP.y2...|
000017c0  88 24 b6 01 66 56 24 ba  34 5a 81 d1 8e f7 d0 39  |.$..fV$.4Z.....9|
000017d0  8a b0 47 99 11 df 31 63  93 31 ef d9 85 9e c9 2e  |..G...1c.1......|
000017e0  d7 a1 e5 4f dc 0a f6 aa  a7 d8 c9 f5 4e c1 17 80  |...O........N...|
000017f0  a0 43 e8 09 ef 2f 45 48  68 f7 e6 ac 1f 27 1e d9  |.C.../EHh....'..|
00001800  6e d6 70 c7 9b 20 d6 0c  0e c4 55 82 e3 73 b7 f6  |n.p.. ....U..s..|
00001810  bf 27 3a 00 ec df 30 d7  0b 6a 6c ff 94 35 9f 37  |.':...0..jl..5.7|
00001820  a5 87 ac 5a 06 91 67 45  8a f4 8b 5a 52 21 24 ed  |...Z..gE...ZR!$.|
00001830  b8 c8 5b 6d eb fa 20 69  61 29 e4 8a 26 25 d8 21  |..[m.. ia)..&%.!|
00001840  7e b3 c6 7e 32 5b 04 e7  92 64 e1 f1 7f 60 b3 23  |~..~2[...d...`.#|
00001850  e3 30 80 36 ce 5e 2a dd  b6 5a 3a c1 3a 82 91 0a  |.0.6.^*..Z:.:...|
00001860  91 99 a7 8e 82 5e 2d 67  e1 ac 0b 87 a6 53 a3 06  |.....^-g.....S..|
00001870  c0 50 ae 8e 4b c8 e5 cc  4a ef 1d 0d 12 66 6a 12  |.P..K...J....fj.|
00001880  8e f2 27 51 a4 eb f4 f4  42 1d fe 06 d0 b4 11 93  |..'Q....B.......|
00001890  5a 53 80 bb fe ad 9a 78  5a ac 33 6f 9e 94 b1 fd  |ZS.....xZ.3o....|
000018a0  93 6b a1 55 c1 b7 52 74  01 40 cb 06 50 44 d0 20  |.k.U..Rt.@..PD. |
000018b0  f5 4d 7f 7f b9 09 78 84  61 29 0c 53 cb 9e e3 51  |.M....x.a).S...Q|
000018c0  c6 da 89 ba c1 f4 a5 5f  ee 54 de 1d 6b ee 97 f7  |......._.T..k...|
000018d0  7f 22 b0 bc f4 09 8e 94  21 0c 61 3a 1b 1d b4 16  |."......!.a:....|
000018e0  02 7f 98 a7 8a c1 d1 cb  6e 2c 5e 26 be fd 27 c8  |........n,^&..'.|
000018f0  71 e9 b3 cc 63 82 c8 fc  a7 7c bf 58 95 26 da 2d  |q...c....|.X.&.-|
00001900  2e 86 22 2a ab bf c5 93  9e 63 97 d0 7f a0 4d b1  |.."*.....c....M.|
00001910  06 a7 60 26 d9 f2 51 33  15 30 25 48 16 47 f9 d9  |..`&..Q3.0%H.G..|
00001920  cb 78 f8 3d d4 8f 2b 21  5a 9b bd fd 2a 4a 1a e9  |.x.=..+!Z...*J..|
00001930  43 ed 7d 57 46 58 03 03  83 db e1 1b 1d ce d5 eb  |C.}WFX..........|
00001940  f8 b2 92 28 60 14 10 0c  33 b9 59 70 f3 23 aa 24  |...(`...3.Yp.#.$|
00001950  45 03 f0 d7 70 a3 0f ed  4e 01 17 95 93 70 5a bf  |E...p...N....pZ.|
00001960  86 46 e0 29 f4 04 be 2f  5b b3 c2 75 82 c3 20 f1  |.F.).../[..u.. .|
00001970  f3 79 ef 96 b9 3a c0 c5  6c 0c 1a c8 7e 91 dc 1c  |.y...:..l...~...|
00001980  0d 59 01 33 d8 d3 c9 d1  bd d7 3c 79 f6 79 d3 62  |.Y.3......<y.y.b|
00001990  0d ca 8b 90 b5 de 56 72  86 90 87 47 f2 f0 8b 91  |......Vr...G....|
000019a0  18 8b ba 81 38 e7 64 33  e9 ee ed 99 a8 46 79 6c  |....8.d3.....Fyl|
000019b0  2a 54 1a 99 69 5a de ff  dd 18 07 13 e2 fc 40 31  |*T..iZ........@1|
000019c0  16 b4 04 9a 3c 02 a1 9f  4c 2c df 16 22 ac 49 d2  |....<...L,..".I.|
000019d0  93 75 a4 54 d6 a5 2e c4  da 49 da bc f6 f2 ac a4  |.u.T.....I......|
000019e0  d9 b3 56 1e 58 52 c4 e4  b0 4e a8 d4 e2 c8 ca 37  |..V.XR...N.....7|
000019f0  bb 8e 33 e2 8d 75 ca 88  d9 61 c3 67 22 f7 80 b3  |..3..u...a.g"...|
00001a00  49 80 fb 25 94 ae 16 da  e3 85 f1 69 a3 4d ca cf  |I..%.......i.M..|
00001a10  e5 6d 67 79 2c a6 e1 20  d3 61 ac 39 1a 93 2b 2f  |.mgy,.. .a.9..+/|
00001a20  d3 4f a0 d0 1f a7 4f 53  2d cf ed 4f fd 31 33 47  |.O....OS-..O.13G|
00001a30  8e d0 75 cb 40 5a a3 98  4c 94 c8 c6 37 77 91 f9  |..u.@Z..L...7w..|
00001a40  51 eb c9 21 fa c1 b7 9d  62 81 3b eb c6 bc 7c aa  |Q..!....b.;...|.|
00001a50  79 2d 81 fa 31 f3 e3 d9  4d 1b d3 c7 49 15 a5 da  |y-..1...M...I...|
00001a60  7c 83 94 a5 43 26 4c 1c  c8 a3 8c d5 a9 a7 a7 fc  ||...C&L.........|
00001a70  f8 e8 93 26 01 12 6e 6d  76 c8 b5 65 4c a3 e2 50  |...&..nmv..eL..P|
00001a80  3b d1 b4 ce 88 de 37 58  d6 08 a3 3f fa f5 be f0  |;.....7X...?....|
00001a90  f1 e3 ce c1 6c c6 08 f9  24 8b a1 63 4b ba c6 6f  |....l...$..cK..o|
00001aa0  7e b2 6d 5d c1 66 5b 66  5a b6 41 43 a0 20 ec 7d  |~.m].f[fZ.AC. .}|
00001ab0  c9 49 68 7e 06 f7 6c 32  da 8f b9 45 41 b8 84 19  |.Ih~..l2...EA...|
00001ac0  15 93 3f 7f d0 0d 95 1d  d7 8b e1 db 77 f1 8b db  |..?.........w...|
00001ad0  1a 27 c7 2d 85 fa c6 69  6d 92 36 ac 70 dc 49 0b  |.'.-...im.6.p.I.|
00001ae0  3a 37 7c 3f 20 f5 d7 01  6a 3d 70 ef 4e 93 bf 30  |:7|? ...j=p.N..0|
00001af0  43 7d 34 5e 26 a8 e0 3f  f4 fa 95 87 ed 2a f6 7c  |C}4^&..?.....*.||
00001b00  14 ac bc 65 70 08 2a c5  cc 15 9e c1 28 57 41 9f  |...ep.*.....(WA.|
00001b10  03 72 b5 9d d1 9d 03 eb  00 ac e9 e5 8a e3 92 36  |.r.............6|
00001b20  d4 1a 86 18 8f 07 63 73  3d 89 cc f3 00 17 03 43  |......cs=......C|
00001b30  87 55 c7 c3 90 48 af 22  60 8c 8e 8b f1 50 8b 58  |.U...H."`....P.X|
00001b40  f6 0e 41 81 f2 8e c6 41  1c 73 1e 68 6d b0 fd b0  |..A....A.s.hm...|
00001b50  4a fa f6 a3 e2 eb 80 be  ea e6 13 23 99 86 b2 0c  |J..........#....|
00001b60  bb 8c 14 bb 74 c0 ce 03  40 06 1a 4f 59 68 93 70  |....t...@..OYh.p|
00001b70  50 7d 58 6a 16 d4 97 73  4c 09 89 1e 95 f1 f7 b6  |P}Xj...sL.......|
00001b80  cb d7 b1 ca be 6a e9 15  98 d3 e3 7e d6 15 6a a0  |.....j.....~..j.|
00001b90  93 16 74 d1 e7 e5 15 c4  d2 59 75 5a ae 41 c3 e3  |..t......YuZ.A..|
00001ba0  fc 72 8f 37 85 40 11 e2  69 61 2a 45 be c1 9e 0a  |.r.7.@..ia*E....|
00001bb0  ff 70 ca ea 3e 31 d2 1d  36 f6 ed 13 b0 de 7b 6e  |.p..>1..6.....{n|
00001bc0  f9 29 3e 6b a3 8a 00 16  9d 0e 06 a7 49 d9 08 d5  |.)>k........I...|
00001bd0  8c b5 27 cc 36 03 34 8c  56 49 f3 cc 7c 95 a1 c6  |..'.6.4.VI..|...|
00001be0  e3 a2 34 16 5a 09 b1 e7  38 46 13 9a 26 41 22 3b  |..4.Z...8F..&A";|
00001bf0  7a e9 0e 94 66 75 a7 7c  d3 4b 30 3d 1a 2e 70 c4  |z...fu.|.K0=..p.|
00001c00  d9 81 4d 31 3e 00 54 c6  c8 79 e0 4d 7c 5b 69 1b  |..M1>.T..y.M|[i.|
00001c10  67 fe bc cc af 93 18 cd  d5 31 42 f6 49 6d 12 20  |g........1B.Im. |
00001c20  9d e0 27 9a b6 eb 4d d7  4f 4f a8 e9 27 9b 60 b9  |..'...M.OO..'.`.|
00001c30  ba e9 ff dc 4b b7 fc 95  9a 90 e7 e5 52 df 72 18  |....K.......R.r.|
00001c40  5e 0f 66 26 ad 3d 4b d4  34 9a c7 12 0b 6b 66 1a  |^.f&.=K.4....kf.|
00001c50  20 be 97 7b cd d0 55 34  03 8f bc 03 f2 6f 4f 1c  | ..{..U4.....oO.|
00001c60  dc e5 cf 8b c1 9c b4 88  da c2 16 08 5e df d4 53  |............^..S|
00001c70  c0 f7 2e f0 ff b3 bd 82  0a 46 2d 56 52 9c 8f a2  |.........F-VR...|
00001c80  c1 89 0c 57 2b fd 45 7a  00 cb 3d c7 1f d4 2a 46  |...W+.Ez..=...*F|
00001c90  3f 73 92 3d ae c9 b7 0a  32 94 14 f5 2c 23 d0 c8  |?s.=....2...,#..|
00001ca0  97 1d 63 df 9d d5 23 d6  0e 9a 69 ce 87 ee a3 32  |..c...#...i....2|
00001cb0  2a 7e 90 09 76 7a 9e b6  14 e1 00 00 00 00 fe ff  |*~..vz..........|
00001cc0
```

*EDIT: now including 1 byte for filename length*

*EDIT 2: golfed 1 byte from decompression script thanks to @nununoisy*

Comment: I downloaded zpaq v7.15 to my Mac from the link you kindly provided, and built it from source, but the compress command you posted doesn't appear to work. The command I have has the synopsis `zpaq command archive[.zpaq] files... -options...` where command is one of `a`, (`add`), `x` (`extract`), or `l` (`list`), and the options appear at the end.  Did you use a different version of zpaq?  Or do you know what command I would enter to replicate what you did?  Thanks!

Comment: I used `sudo apt-get install zpaq` on my Ubuntu 18.04, and that's what arrived. Help message starts with *ZPAQ v1.10 archiver, (C) 2009, Ocarina Networks Inc.* Apparently both the supported options and the option format have changed. From reading the man page, the closest current equivalent would be `zpaq a g uncompressed.txt -ms`. `-ms` is for backward compatibility with older zpaq versions. I cannot find any equivalent to the options I actually used, which were `n` (don't store filenames), `s` (don't store SHA1 checksums), `i` (don't store file sizes), `q` (no messages). I'm updating Answer.

Comment: Thank you!  I'll try that out later today.

Comment: `-ms` didn't work (that turns out to create a file longer than the original; I think it doesn't compress at all, plus it adds a header and footer).  The best was with `-m3` or `-m4`, which yielded a file size of 8264 bytes.  (`-m5` is supposed to be the best quality compression, but that one was 8302 bytes.)  There's probably some way to get down to the 7360 bytes you got from the older version, but I haven't found it yet.

Comment: I should add that the difference is more than 900 bytes, which doesn't look like it's just metadata that wasn't included with the older version. It must be some more significant difference.

Comment: `-noattributes` takes off just an additional 3 bytes.

Comment: The filename is stored (presumably so that it can be restored when decompressed).  Changing the original filename from uncompressed.txt to u got the output down to 8261 bytes.

Comment: All websites I have seen claim that `zpaq` has the unique property of being compatible with future versions. That seems to be achieved by storing the decoder as part of the archive. I assume that's where the difference comes from. (I tried `zpaq` too, but I didn't try an older version)

Comment: @MitchellSpector the `-n` option in zpaq 1.10 avoids storing the filename. I got the exact same output starting with a filename `u`. https://pastebin.com/7v7axyHa is the complete usage message from my zpaq 1.10.

Comment: @mypronounismonicareinstate Certainly it's future compatible in that archives created in an old version can be uncompressed with a new version. But the commandline syntax is not compatible at all.

Comment: @RossPresser I'm not sure you understood my comment correctly: I was referring to forward compatibility, not backward compatibility.

Comment: @mypronounismonicareinstate Also, it would appear, surprisingly, that the quality of the compression may not be as good as it was in the earlier version (unless I'm just missing some option, which is likely).  When I compress the genome text with the new version, the output I get is almost 900 bytes longer than what Ross got with the older version.

Comment: @mypronounismonicareinstate Do you think they're actually including the decompression code in the compressed output now?  That seems counterproductive for actual use.  The decompresser itself should just be backwards compatible.

Comment: @MitchellSpector What I suspected is that over time the algorithm got more complex, increasing the overhead but decreasing the compressed part's size.

Comment: zpaq's design is that the compressed file contains decompression code. `Many intermediate versions include compression improvements. This does not break forward compatibility because the decompression code is stored in the archive.`  The ZPAQ standard defines a virtual machine.  In fact, there exists a [zpaq configuration](https://encode.su/threads/1211-Compressing-pi) that "compresses" a million digits of pi into 159 bytes ... by ignoring the input and instead computing pi from a series.

Comment: Btw, I copied the wrong number before. Using a 1-byte filename gives me a size of 8246 bytes.

Comment: @mypronounismonicareinstate Then I'm not sure why you mentioned compatibility at all. If you're referring to our inability to find the options in 7.15 that reproduce output from 1.10, I emphasize that the option structure is thoroughly different now, as of version 2 I believe, owing to a rewrite of zpaq to rely on libzpaq. We've been unable to find a document about converting old options to new ones. I've posted a [message](https://encode.su/threads/456-zpaq-updates?p=65359&viewfull=1#post65359) to a huge "updates" thread asking for assistance.

Comment: I'm not disturbed by not being able to reproduce the exact output from the older version; as long as it's still decompressible, that's fine.  What bothers me is that the new version is producing output that is 886 bytes longer (which is 12% longer) on this particular sample.  If that's because decompression code is being included, I think that's a bad design decision. @mypronounismonicareinstate

Comment: From all appearances, the decompression code inclusion goes all the way back to 1.00, so that decision alone isn't the problem. Certainly 1.10 includes it, because it supports arguments allowing you to use a "configuration".

Comment: -1 byte using process substitution: `zpaq qx g >(cat)`

Comment: @nununoisy Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

## python 3.8, <sup><strike>161</strike></sup>169+1+<sup><strike>287</strike></sup>289+<sup><strike>267</strike></sup>193+6985=<sup><strike>7702</strike></sup> 7637

```python
from zlib import decompress as D
from itertools import product as P
from functools import reduce as R
x=289
c='AGCU'
d=open('f','rb').read()
print(eval(D(d[:x]))(d[x:]))
```

where `D(d[:x])` is

```python
(lambda f,
rest_len=[265,7,8,24,50,10,6,134,14,24,229],
genes_len=[7097,1274,276,76,223,62,122,122,420,39],
cut=lambda s,x:R(
    lambda acc,n:[acc[0][n:],acc[1]+[acc[0][:n]]],
    x,[s,[]])[1],
cut_out=lambda x,n:x[:n]+x[n+1:],
C=[''.join(i) for i in P(c,repeat=3)]:
cut_out(''.join(i+''.join(j)
    for i,j in zip(
        cut(''.join(c[(i//r)%4] for i in f[:193] for r in [1,4,16,64]),rest_len),
        cut([C[i-32] for i in D(f[193:])],genes_len)+[[]])
    ),13468)
)
```

and the file `f` is [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/19-l1Tbg44H0Bc1TFXXPwfvS1HSuSESPO?usp=sharing) (produced with decode_1.py).
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dXxnW9xMEu33/RUkEwwGtaRRIGODAZtkg8HgwUYtdRtskochh7@@V6fqaLn3w919/AIzCq2Kp05V6/K@e3xxHmWXnf/@13cuznoeTk9sz8nZ5UWn21O58uLssuOurnqKq57F/8gBJ13X6V5cnF41R112LqrrsotDtvQQf31e/j@HdFx9hMMRX/9zNxNm@X/KmaGF5Q/fhv5Tzdihu/ZdXn6r/2Pad5X5077LoqB9Z@L6l6R95/xz@/ziY/1B1L7zZfvOpvWhxXH9m7H1J/WhRfFYH1v/YnEF@2G4fVe6@sy8/jTrnuCq7bvAVZv1EX7xL46pv2nV/2L95z2WgJ9T9Wn1waa8qS@Lm7m52fq3@nibLdUnxvXNy3ohrnV52m6vfj3bOqovXX@d4/w8el8fHG/VFwj2cUt9qCCtTy2L@o9qob5JfcOqhQvirln9S329zHb35uuD6j/LsP4zbZ/X5@Go@qCi/lnWly/wrPXZeb0Il@B29ecWotpXQVTxnH7rw4P6/BLH11es/L7K09vrbxBXfdlCpVvhWeKJT@1OfoZV16c7LGEAS@LdID1Tf2rCsf7jelVQTg4xPD/pao3buNXncpkp8RQbHzv1BXKqJzj@Vd8prDXrW/gF14R4IbF6DSUeBx9AX/7s9FD1XCZ/9KJl/Z3N8f041lafkVU/a2E5np/bsfrLWk6Z27xuD9X/l8dz9a09Tq3v6SATLAdfQPgBxIpzoZXsEOfXNuShMDyyfVSp4/IW@sqc6qkKoM76VlBr/FSL27R2zjM@SHKFpffzGWGC5dVgfYhIAXcs39RHeTVIiB8WXNWPESSqrdrGa70VlRpGUU5D8atn9/WP@ELV4TKs/kjFksWD01v1IooIN/gK11FPyEL9B/OBV3i7rgKz1dSRygYisMGtGgycymaw6/rCEFTerf8IrT5KUOrhuLpYfwRjkftl@jC4oE1URs6v3tdOUyUXtav5dLU@tFBDzUMxDuol2b09nm93ip76gPoyPlOTyQM1CTE7fm4yPFTpp/VU5/UnHAQ680Ht2lXRu/J/Xcng4aef9C@Egwon5XMaFxysASqp/Nw07SNSCaWQS6X2b/zd@zF95sC86GcSVgK9A@4WQAayPLs63AcDGtALBf7zLWQ2DSPRgGM8nGyk/qNQI8/sxxH/@qxiD9WK2lgZ5nomYkiR1msw6WJ96eIyVWspo7l1XTtCFQKMqRDEYPj57NIl1qb@@v//d6eRz1QPCItw@WhM1@GcWiKiTpV9Uu3DUE28fFqHuNJkv2AKCDuILeVn9QKx7XwYqldhGviL3Z@B7S6oy2V0a29PNYzBF6v6ca09X37R701e@3iV7uK88Fkd00rU@3Wv2ioy@ERrFPFuD1/Iig9phQWu@tDufKdZpWrLVbLzFasvnnewlhs1jCLJmTQgvEQPx2n4Eo5hkGMqxB@74@eul1SXFrquKnFPo64N80VwLqpfuOzFJ31iuFBGv7b1ZYJQA55vvYOacoQTtRGHtGH8pjojPsENIHwELnwGKZRldIif4lqFKrEIm@xlNVLB@2tXaiMYnWswlSTrQjUVkzDBFO2u6irPVYmyEKOxI4/7R2GAX35vYt2dZ3jOucaXIMIxtbd7o64oayjaQ7cD6sWlUWuS8Jc2nvYRqlezLWDTSAVIRTB7W53Fd2lXvRxP4bJhuN@jOgPMFsrJvSZYcXY7jqV0NdjjyhAN/CBvqWiCaA12ig8HT2j7CEbVpyZhaiyDT1buIGIq9tfq2j7WnIfUid@LfA/HrjDgtjSzAQcU6Z2mN/iSZPjai7vjWOcqNPkV1qzmAAcz2dYLhHSn4oYr@Gp3awX6yLJ9ZIk/mv2QaPE0FZTfUkPCTaEhGBQkJRk07Y7eXvZBGx8zhTY41cV646zonCBT4tlXVGWIVWV0pLfJMwEuEIkZJxiJJwp9FjgC3DAQQ5yA5Qk0@QBzP4EUt3og67M7LHxRxSr5zbQ7Jze6UIAMK/5qFYmVsYoOT1WGiJJAWRA7LACmIb8XqraswLKLg6w737dFTRr9aXl4HlwiHSBEtzTvZ/ny2ds9ZlZE1SAFZPI/me1gvAVlDLBXMKVB2FU5nTGh2pWtzm88/v6UBhnvFjUzluGi@rlxQKZQfhn01r9AtnYSVr0GF//HVVbn6h6SbCwX6TTT2GgUaoXJxQAAyNFYFOJjUZ7QbZl0fDh5NakhwOdrGrMQSWBcuDlQiBxvtjT@@fC9RgEv2GYH4nuzoAchbkj0qcZhUDDp@FwDuLd9qk4nD5JN6G3EP0WhH3D6SEehXJlet4EAi2dNdVm4hP/sLY6Mq1Yz39X1ZcSwQTAMvfhkdJhxGkcJRkrcDhx6SpNeXu63vsMTURKU271q9Sa7UVVWpkcXbEK1blwLKVuCU/Ab1tGPsLmG@y7t9a9p5EEcFT8OuprygnT4voVf56FLmAv0A5vNYgTIYnNBbbsMopsd2IKsCLAtI16Hzbj0xqwQRaXLiiYFeOf/9qttqXgG1Xqd/4Nz0z/wgOLlE4xqTIXjEmSg1rGamABnGEOZSMi8IcRD0sn3IapSnwfRNE/Mp5HfilykzBEwffod54TqDBJ4sjAZUeUDYOfVJD0@WFcUUVQf9QJBuTQCObwrx3bb53XOL9wO3CiRuDEF8czQFYwaWp7vKEK14f4nArjiZVJDmABqwc7jmjdxe4TmrLr6vqlGVgZva1DfUUiO74K4JaGz/w2kMb61oc/rY9RZxn1rt8c0xELpyLpwrzx8u5qq@2XV4tF3PcJIiVOqN0JIUJDEHdyi9UejS@GI/Zz7gcfcUiXCAWE8eTmssSWLvosNnGt@RWQtYL2Vu4bR1p5@jrWW9KmcYTymYeGU@CsAmBWgeNoeGj3QpQXBkx5symON1IilCB1SSyULa0zGXnIwwovr6@@HQZcE8IJqjmjq0T9NJ2KPuHeAKioIfsN9klWY0qJq3vs7At2YSwEUMZdaNCDM5gFFGKjb1do90tAetP5q4nTpwJyCxZIoUiA0jNgMtDu/v2puzQAiM7vUr6kQFiQBImChi5SdxIrPETphDNYsq8eaHPnArXc0kItXA0K4f5pfJMZCu1IvWj27io8h6bEeCpRFCBw7SwnZynTuEfErH4dD4EvmQs8qEhEIJoIckhVfVaNB63RSgUgt36E@nDGApbVWbyHDQVZh8cALcMFHPFq0BAMYhNsKRYE85ln9uuJK6AxFJgjvEDvuKLVz2CUEQMzKv/w64Aqt@rdgG78G5Z@x9PPvtIapbwhVXlfgLsJNmpGE0jtoUXSFGqZ4WNbyE@HUln@gu1@qTCslB@SXvD9DuKvu36tlBq4PpjgvINQC1pTp5TQzbPTwm5ZTKKJHBHctqDFdgaLOEIWO9bsMVlnBIkWJxfSAPpqLVAwFPE5qifQv1LCGjyZpsunpzS7MeRDBuJSKhsm2pbjUlD2/tcDGZerVDemZvhqMCIXDExALfRMKYrWqxlcX2/h8F37zk@ENKdDR1XKSTDApQWAVyapceBqCouxZsXLVOofkgajyAToRgXGWftGrANWYyGtqLQqibC/r/gBd7kAipxPE1ALTdyjgksLKl5QSgr0A/th4CjdHzYIkgPuaaFEfxUhcrvRSQNUuTAlHiFkDd8dDEdLcxgnZnxgOknU0iCpO@Kwh3rUgDjMPi5DAItzE7iE9xm3As17g5S9a@JQIulLfQkdlTvgAw85hflm6rRFJyBaIzQB8hOk8HvAcy1rVEi8TlcO1ggM1ZizAZyuziLDTg@Dhorv3auuivWBB1HCjGcq0Lhf0Cxdj1cEjQziLbRdfUmMw6yqeJ5uDW6db7Y5nRrVaImfRgqYDmz0UunyE67w8IopI1JOQkKpy7hl6@4v7n5DBCJtS4gqePQnUikWHd0iZ1m/gQR7Jb4h8@jQ2iI6xqHJRBYOoGpQChABdsydcNKC/wFfKAYh4SQtdSZKowEWeoZqld9da1tWZFxEpGdMoiUyYiTMsPN9/vYF4YKn2ywEsKe7vgSLmx69Z3BIUOKXE6kR1TSgBk0RGgOFlIUmnLOhRxCFYPtQ7VdmMLklyQaxYABbfYCVBHsCCRXyDGP1Hc4ytHmG95vFcnywPAmJ1xUqL8/2K7IT2kloCtFP@KEZ@rgsW43c/Tu/oHgjmyaDaLxxJ4kmglX2N@37pX2X0Bdrgc8PSzNYZb@L1mzx6i@cFeEn@6YIz84P5IAf4qOJHvVomReGZXG0Ihw30atFio1utyQVaSrK5gEimBcMM9YoChy4Q1BZ@aIJzUfIOVryJNb3TZzCgFIALhJTJdjSOSlb2Zy/qPbWsJeSXM19PX2CnkR8BAIoRJsz11ZHXCkVil1M0YpEJYdg23WMLIHvFNlIKR6pRIXOzpesNUiOwZXerGQFoAtjEoJgSwE2@AYZc5YOskooDEr3pXKXmIjV02dQNT4hrtqsxq4qh2mxdLyJlHcRXa7e9p@FICFqwnBlpj6x8S6trdRE0sjty2papFAbQWvuL5YyB54BFwIIQ5wt/SZxpNYUEFlVW2nenS/TlJ/0FPlv6YS2aqvQR65qPBy5RW99DkGdYMkqDEKVTOMjasbxWqYFHEIKg9fUSUjhC@oleHk81JuR0OGgdss/9yryaJGAXCBhLgkAiebE4qfIqxR@kCpXS9YcyB8Jg@PWNbebEvPsFDxOWGlOEFAIvaCPcExWNL1cdalRXaCjNswF8eKlOHQTjehYAmwRirwqQmkPUfrnEW7ekrqqasko9BRjA2JtKMTzoCFix3AzeEZ06HpPmE8hnCGzm6NcjewstmLhgaSk1QEagGs6j2Q3I4QPJA9RXSL1I92DxhAdlI8rFn/FA9zA2XA00FEJmvYZzXVGVKuDLENby/INE14zcMFRoP6oX@CoFvZm/0xACyjKPjo6XNcc4VA9FzvCQx2l7aB/lMHjMvPU717zl3SfGqJJVZPUGjgq0Df@Am0qvS7j6SFci/CXAanghDtKBMrLbvyi0/apRBUgSztnF89o3GdKFS62f/SRfly1MqK6FyzQqjqopeewtPDEqWLHGV7oEhF1peOGL@H5BrbpwZx9V7DBR11q2TX2Fm86eqRd6nFQCdsKYhekKp6cn1BsN4F3BbITYBGAnPSkyrTCWqjpWISPjCBUsHRXBK5YNlOQBN63vMPQd3jpC9jm@pZYzkN9ChBdMOInq2Iad/kXc00yvqx1V/hcbP8lHfXyL0IxCUtpWaAtY9EVcfKBhTRgt1x5KtQT1EWwBCRtwJCdHLqRtpYLNWtOCaqMvCAjWrJE2RtEB5kugrBSQM7hR8uezFAW53g6AxbIyqsz2r0F2CwAejaCI8B8iRev5HdgkZx/nuvrgRiqxlzGNFYWApBOGqVRRdBWicxCuke6NH9E1TC8UMkksS07VrvIINXfR2nyiuISfKjfUAFBiumRNncWH7xfIg6Neyi@NWqNzC2CFLBJtKkR3R3FE6T/uoMXkpjfPVeS4ZhVofqrIb/mGagcCS86XG6zOrkCpfubMX01zWTQSjI9rCsvjXkYD@Hg@qmaCFAmzyvxbvWPAJRsPghGAO/PrM1BDsUXevXo6YDeB/KR0IiyxqPSkzakaBgrMrJwAvqz@aDiVR2uAkyPSQrYs90H@2BPy44gQLp/bJMCottViFIvssQ63KLbBRGTRzDSJyIKOhpTmW8RNTb9TKhrUOAXTh7Rf3cAHGBJCT4K@dLmmJu6kRQ6TQj2NpICkWhXCea1p0Cr8y0LOMqhAa1W6gwFrAgigAkCFbWUpCUX3WdWgnDg85ulEWqdrLIlbmyQjq8vexy8qjar8ilMnt@80cJTsKUntVey8QRRc5nWlu3E/8MNoIhQGJCVQjWmhuSIZREPjdMk2nerFJxE7S/ZaOtBHioWN1VTt/Aq7RxVZ8ugRNyrWh6U2Dxr6a@wQRkbiy7bmkIHkQlyClUILFhh9//4Zer9uktrd@EcNhTZn/x@GaVp7QgYL28cw5LIHZBWMDdj5SqNOwb4NkJdNDgnDWvQOWFF6RWrdnzCdCSwf/LqBy6@kmrSKIr5@p4aTiUzEHSAsnG9k3MBrRrWtQCOdsDjV3pVaeY1OHvrBchZojyefCEOjZ/xnnCxR9MTsK3a0@wUJDRVrhURfFH2s1TPFQhbIDwIWZjQnqpeW5tTDijp@EUvzTlK@1RCS8fGrcJ@AEaeUq6x@W4SiBRiP/FKjP3xJQk74r@9Q/5RmVjm93FEHl/Ikdepg1r5ZpUTAN2cpeKHqB2wrbFgK9hUT9QhEDOsHSWJWRyz9IbhycFQKOjcejsCsoC1HJt40rc@Iqd@x7LFqa7DnwkwAm05xKqEkTI865Jlac181GCECVPHn71imjPRUmvbL9O2txgnjvgCpp9e8I1g/icrhjcSc8yt9Miu9wIDNebk/Ul@IggbVhPhLfqiYAbYpX9vJTUSC@UfgpnVNGp70SFFN7r/htAM1LmLMdGESkVo7Eki6v2h7WbAPIFTEvARk476MPNMLJJMIqVr0oz7@ePgCF0bEkcyPaFqkC2@ZBqR2WSVhnnT7VDY2nL5TN5OqXmrhFYg6foCHfLpWi3QkjK22cpWFTZhVy3JeT/VZn4rEp8HqR5jM1rXq0ac7LOM5zQGjNJwaCoI59poIbMraad5CILMkGaR3L3UyklsC5iLfmYSYBjau1AnwdZXsNlMAqw0SeW46b@uKUcvgBncGJ2IcgA6oCFiK5BHbNw536Fc/Er6f9zfly4FZJ71FwPG/aZr8YG9Ok1bZOoXB3TB0ukxtHEFHtMAurZOrcvILykfAEdYSAk4GyBOZ15BlgMyCuiAaWp4vFGELLeT61WsqTi6V6W67vSVPPbqpUb1k1SINcClF9uCH0meFUwtRE/1UbUpWEVQLH5YOTPiLkyoFp2ayqWaowWn6lvBStO723qzgcnNku8NtUgWC2f8JE3rIAS2kn/z@8SdLW3R4UNrqxMMP@La9O/qjRVTWAJB0WsWXoUsrbQY8TtKL45CChHyNSeDBXDNE7PSuUKv1ZgkK26bCYR/hN46FeJqZefVbYZ6thnbhFcTGhZYeAysjLDU8sXh4wGOMA@PIjEU6p9hE2G7OLglPmZ29@6UKL8KFjWZiaV8BROMfVYuTBwVnGSSjZ7sad1xTU8d3GkOEmwW1p3E8wORFCmNOl2aRIZKTGRIM@cM2@xdYnBDQ4Vs@r@A7RBP/gPUOY5VovLhpTbiipUqNpeSglLC3iGYu72FjCPAmB6qrossjlpq5iliyG8JhYZ@Y2b1yplX2bh6BHD6Z3KxiRR84ZpMO6K0EgEuTzRqtP6WMo7aEDDbKP0v@zZgEORXlUJgiRhsabI6rOE40lfYTiiIxnnz9e7vtdHk5i6IcLIXMnpYih67XGkyYlUhXoh0FLZMqN3Z3p/RD03IVNywn40P8OYfYgHEE8BjGzUCgMoe6o0@ECGaLm1M8R84i2Gg0KpgznVunq4ZMUiFnkoQDOuOkatbQzMsUdDM2WT425eGkhkVfqQAQhqEoqd4BNFxvii5vds4efMEB21LIXOdntQjOggktSrzp/n33Ful/VPVg4o0GKjxJrCZHYPzgLfFwrm0EmS7zqkHBFWiDA0oJTQOVR5c4o/y5z3yDhVaYKAwxPBGwEBF2Ih4nIi45VCVjdCgGzRWJqdbs7Ds1bCfju@/Z5c@@PZ7PkDwXYGqJ4a1eLgDnF/hFTc1ZBaQlXR0h90Z2VYJFFGrUQqkluR5sqgz6xCQJ4tvBq15aNC4nIxjZ5D3hFBRm7xFo/iEZh18Abh84alPS8SUJo4dovvReHpJbDjmuKL3Vy9lfr/xoEI7J1Gf/dvbzGqnht/9Ixitgd4NwBv2uZHWCrpAcPJHBdM@cQJAi2/28YFc0J@GGQjfv2yFISuMzdZKi4RN1nDFoukb6nLBrMTfbM/akSQPOVnCCSgIOxmma3mVgp2ni8eaJHpvpgFD7O8JOMXGsUUFCl38LB3aDmrFlBiECGVHAHaMo/eY5AyB1PFiYKL4/ZY/Vaw4qq47M3UwoxM0bEAvvqDHp0AJTNRKK5AiLKa4AZigkUMDRYZP/RpxMj98R7ziOJqc6m1gL6RuO6pLvJfzIpXWWtTsY08CHniQC/KIWE/6nwSdjVkhofdBesCEMomSP42S0CRsxqT3E/0JGLA8lufwVZLu5u76qca9CuMiT/Z12e1sfvUhnNZEIOPV2hbVcipHUKjIy4hxxMJaNFhmSw@paPxtwzI6dsO2eAMRj3L/gCF1mf3dIieJ5UGjVuGB8m7xfqqYhvZ1Eo3uVyfimkMGkfaT7IqNfsOZyibOx5tOm5lzxcRk0NWQjAiXrjIxUrLJVlUiw@aAxWmiIBrjY9tDBAB7p9xYkiZyejmJ8wbxRpJOb3ypJCRHEgc6cYBUA2jI2VXxjv6y641ibUd0HJafmBYfmG5yFR5/NNlEwf51XrIqfiKOR2q0hnVQZ@rcP0ljBj48QCvxuqYivTJqpii9Y8Tpqj9r6h6ZTNUXJx5IOXx7J5iXExyS4srSjUpGCVpzqeach62gvVh0QmSi3C26vX1pnn6dAB0hTR/D/KMvdUlF14Bgf6kucD2x@O0qavQXQLAcwZdg5YxHDlokUs6VaUJmSjYYSPKaXdeqFZLGzE@9fCxzrsC/DtU4YSb00paPPRAQyEFCeIwbsyiTVhaasID1We8qKMXLI2DZiZOC2jP5QLJI/ECIN@FuMCORMFjmUZ4L4lPxEYCdI9lYaYx2Z5SLdQNvCHwLApNgWgcQqKVzs7w0xK@RuHnCrAzz5G2TxEVF0VxcjFSqwpMF/PEOeZQSWgIm078362A05gYz6LriW0ggjVBSqax/NcIIz1jnjuYfB53@9Grml5xboA1sZeO5/OIZs7bJZnme7z6nxC@5PNFtLV7pguwRJNKkmWIBEuxr2pB8iBNXo3p8Onh0tvboeGlrjF9k5J3JLzYhlhq551KPrRnAKwmsi1gxzKOH5mBqW5SaILDoUkubvp9cWorGnb9mboXXJDpiCw8meZJsUjpnepiTklkqyWmY3OhffaNNIDF0uZmsCozo2P3waazq1FQfaRIGE5i77p7FRtpvEahE6Vr9PusGl2IohE6aM0LWrwdfNAIG6/dHi3HF4dAYP/MuSCtEp2d8j@Rcxd0fsWeKugJ4ZWzQ@GF@a6Tt/agZIexebmY4@Fv4yI1Q2f2jeNwJcMXcRLnAOJxrW5KfTOUKdvCGvYGZUdsKn5bdSMN@rgKAyi2GzenFtUtPQor3huluz@2nPCGdPStZ68djtRKCpJbAPZKGxCAhBZ6RZ03j7IjxBuf2X7XnPmgHN1JztPIs22f9YIEeqPHrtcefYRGZJwtqU3IB7bdWZ1jM1ngC@2kNCw5SrzqtLakvb1N1W@R56jubY8vQdS@Y1fJ1Lw888nt8R1kTGVJqhNc/5T8FZ2sRDMzN5UHpKoavjyKIkRmzUE2@EEtwfjvwEW384Vkb8Ag27goDDhBMsB1s0RNeUofE7BmyMUDoyKWX2psOB6Lz4v2qVAt1pP4Pse08WlRN4cM8iaLaBjTLcC@Y5HdMmjuwpSYanWGa72bP76THNpoInMCgktSWgbPGU8WJpM04hu9PQha71NsQeqGSbGxKqhYpKqKCCVFrFoVYtwbsao32TqAqS3az0RXYCqzucARLHMqQMsSKzcqvRogBfViT33E8YB8OcMHIcYyhoXLGGUxffYMzPnYm7dtVaBJc5XaIoL52SfYfm/Q3326gdt3EroBrzpJYndXYuO8kS9t0N5xVdur7BrqAwGTkDoIxZ9Q1SVcVmsvZEBsR@lcceUocKmvkntEJzTjSa/zUF2WuwflmXbisxyB/svBqNRgKO09F1BTtNNAikpCS@LKqmsJ@H/r6roxYYVBfoHhN1hNccPhdY65c31aSlURG/xcMtiyaHVA7WkhkJkvmGB5KNY98@tbtTmOxt9REfe4EOpyqogmsEnJeoGM993g5Isaf/INcJtt0SnRuT/XeyuUJGD@4lXy0vgw2sLjGkD0czIEdlW2fRD4wjA/MWkztCoYDwty4J/7bQD62w7TMAcC6l6tyFMNFSDt4dAyvmiE04prCfufkEtw9AxCatpXN6XfANPGM5@1uPEWoJGTlzW5s9374gzqbx987r7jJpO8ccWA3lb0zcFAO8SdMsDRm4UOX4JQ0ABvsSsmYvkTQm2p21/qaIUodAMNKm20IvLcD0954xm5ANkX2CZu4Ft7a7nKfHNizE65wNfFuOwstnDmSVGNVMZzS0VU4LkConAxyQj2ltz3LfXDbP0Bxwr4GUbiRDApBvEJPMhojMYtzAufe0AnbDsmxgRXXqmERqOQCRJRgMwDCaRCAA@1II9UImI0BORXPP3yhyBuIAA@uyww/lS9OhKQQwZzI2VOxdfiI45xC5kS4VBiXSiwlErX1VYZFiKLzidEQlNboMEaxxu5bsSckmP9DDEPmkcVxph8Y0e7bjRQTuEh04GPz/2k5u7JULR@iStBZtfGYfW3oRN2xj2iWwgBW6/EaUiTKmHCRV3EyxV09qYnlT4Eit1f/AFgMyFipoab5Dx9KwJCMvKZxcRFktTxDmIutXCF1Vz@sOuFwb/ISu7ll/8WbYbOAiSGsYV7BublHmwbgSRn3L1oN0wDFoWMlcg@EuednyWjSDxdi4LlclhpNxOsP6xHM2pOD0pAy@csihCrOpvhN2DjKFfAIBMFXh2SMVUrHpVuREJrYJZrRtIV4D5n9JhQXzqwsZXJB9ShQ@MrncwmBpFSSpep3JpihzJztMJK5Kg95yc5fh/mpZuzSE73fp5naZcJr7ulyzrTbio4XiMN3xt7IFSErVXc2Vxt5gehBzNTLYBM8EESU5JHoDjjbvzs7uNnuaOMUMWgVQQSwqpU5iTJOjRVxU3S8cSE4W077@9L2eiqv7Kp/ceD7itE/Zt3fGDmOWPxEkS58dECRbYXoruS3NtTtP31hkYwTBpNjWgEkI2RdqHre9VlMF31lgA@mKYi4e9JjsBE0l/n/9bUjoChqZ7uEgbxVsn6hqDdp@rrU9KNkTg3wSwKIBomGhv7MG5B7fXuhiJVz4oy45XOnrsDtQgfWSuEbUIpRESzgnwJ/0WaO@VN/VQbszx9cveBaJ3qy2O9s7TSP/FafKFFxKXF28BfxLLfsoTSsThuHIvUowIqMkOBjVowyG8ELSAIXhR@/YtOLsv@GEg3By9V/3nE/NjecsTEW0Zj5M9k@2h46/s5UACF8V3wePh2leMWc94lUS6OjRlangh0XCOFwML7EQH4GkJN1ie451DTXU9/qHIx8t1bs0U8llShVGMlYm0LFw35LNH1ao/gIXbYY@pH2SXyptmUm0kWGKX9eMtWDli6Ymz9vtQW5HFvi@x1kX93WNc3Bl2lmldkyXQ34xu6GxcGWz8Y@H9rnEZviV/TRDgIxuSIqmuHUfXnFzyV0WFpPQeUBihwOrMsIZ9pEKDhUZG60HhjTbunSXpH8yDIxhYu6YiploZPcT54jkdHilnbhlEDAzdz/@t2@Em75IZATxyt6ark76gtgXX/jhTa4N24gdoHsKgWfAsjLaBHwlu8GA8mXUVzYgGLJteAr0S5BVfM70qLsfcY@Lp9kcl5y8OH7L@qxc@faWYz@W@KRkpAqvt2Zl/u2t4v0cxFeRNWzic9NLWFRhaUX4Uw/JitFDjfVF9Z0EVNI@3/3EBBd8@MwhYbITwrgWtwN/x7hJsHTAg9WJDDJgL2bw8XXSTCbL/Rc8wwl5VAi1CqUR9fZzHzbEmKuBpBlWYjtbJtr@NiAd4XVr9LUoR8DKk77hde6fkLBtbsgJ@Asl@/GHTLtxF5Vsn7PyWpindgcMZoBEIR0L4YX3H3ZfdyoLU8YXfIjUZIx6FPWmub5pfb1QtzQ5BhuEljTDHOMzfyUWjUMYyeoCB51zs8mpgcJ9/MOWQIvNI6STMjyahmYf1a8Dt8bxEzkStJl0Kuj2ZTE50D7fUo9I/czR4ARliLIWOx6yOu0Mc1eezFTgCSpsoQmm1ZJkZwZqgipYhXHkF6PqRhW3@OVmp3kfjaRE7F1x@QtnegSbnKKQMA@zRARCqiCKOvi3ANQAo9v2dI7tUom2p7cn3Vl5k8Yl93em82ibyQt3sqYNTC1Infe5IVP7ue0yIjdnVS4yt@Gp8gzsfFl8@tsrQ6XjP2kzJb3G9SBF490AMgrsJqTthL82ZolQq98cKaxgKWVGalkGE6pegOJhVjay30NY6Jj2KBvI0G8tD1@Zi6a2z8OB52ZQ5qV5ZcU93n8kOzIDTvoEn4/1XMHJEuev9Y@SMpHWH7WYlX/ZnJEuz5s7Gm25OKxpsczljQ1P3IafceNDss2dQXKebDF8RjVY2b8YHEZvo@SOF@E8q7XRXSy1BP@PaXeISLh/2Y4qHIBs8INOZQoa3ujDgyV6bsb3NInxf9O3JKSTTXVPFtkz/3lagmxQ4N40nzY2hJs@KCSxPv7APgtYZNPA@PRg6h37o8ksI5Jd1IuUoFhdhGxcPf6afX25hUyxCsZMmPud4g6ZLMlXUWfjZTyyl67Z2IKZuzzE2CaIvAaqV9zKZCtONJSY6aow9IyQAZssOIAooRS@jykU35i/o6h0vvkZycbhVRkCMOyTTFOurhy9vgQBziN7H/DmIRmWI2IrWy21hLzs6CcmhDKkPi57JGSCJWrJtP41Jw@at@pEz5NsV2X6IDIkBIRXuVmUrr77E9Ev2yKUDDktk7H5ajS1SS7nWzr0hSeYPio2mk2NJNsz7JQvZT/uLlNP8XHxH@k47u0WsBJys4i8Wuw366G46UfPc2zEs/bXl0d02SJsqf4qS5ctiG3TUY46QCcu5PRMznZU/DpVVnEPgpM@4ChYIn@1omBIrN3qUxj7m6Ubd406O4CJdnSdrLl9/7VJi/Nqt7I/GMbcup9Urr@/V5N0Vbz7joOzZls1CrBmqUXey8l/yXi/hAnk653KVOa5gPazXr5ZJTy5grk1s36Z/pONjK2DR12@WAws2cr@iRHU0jKFAk5MyCNSuxhT0541jBqca6n7J7vCCyZm4u/l2frvC0juWOkLJ5OokJq7QtQK385gI3hy1sNtnhFdNmL3L097OPsCe0mx0xk7arOmV@rXiexTAqqItHPKSlj2CkMieFudECb2fyXxkdYdQEfCrMVqXdBtyqq7LrjaeGWaDLJGvV8O1ScCTAYLtg@4tdnRjBM3y1kkQ5rCkkGWzRqVmqQH0eDzA3YIMm5sYToVBgZbkSU2OU4XVej0gEkw0oac4raRHJ2YNB15N0X/8dw1TKBhtHo5R1NF0IRY7hJWWYIJcnscchdwj2aoEMjBL40u8pW8c2t0izuAPAuBFt8m0LiE7KA5wwYqwWIGCD1Imk4IMV7zcqmC@L8OpV0E5ACUHEY7CreSYxTU9/@Dc75wpl62PcpWp5EjFlB1Or/im0BklIVvkwlqUIzxd8jLiq4WfirzkEf7u9no@BRekhAd7X3lcIek4@H3ApyurvbQRgla7NXKcKDQlAWLM6/GVmRj2IknCU/ajH8PkfbMHqGsb1qFHi9xERcHJyOTUo5wueAmXMEKeDVPhRaxvPUDXoVXj7jmpWruZvKRc3XCey1waqqU/QuXelqgvf4uudv8nZoAQK3n/gUpxzhGIfNYHPvJ2PY14bJm3UrKWOmvrKqyK76cryymHuhx0aiMCs8jpAPzF3HT7iSHLgP/ort/7K7IXoqJr0pNWbz9Q8Y0EG9D2S62yckUIZVln9p@M0PJUAN7CLbfqfRTvFevCtRMLPkQGRyWcjBie7hkLzflIKS8ScoM7zZvyuEUBGdlg6DbPk@/CyW7c/obbnrX1CuoSlooliSjCatwBIoxx/sbchDgsv8cm9Vl9LFcbkaRrGC7j9hAJqMJ8p4uzF/IcGuLLzcBvynlFx1ZXuAi0eFCRgKqof9cdk7Ou8PupjgdXhyufkzeHY6M1D/vJuuf/PLUnQ9XI6Nm1CT5yH//@38A)

Posted here only to show grouping [nucleotides](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nucleotide) approach as the decoder overhead is very large.
So let's start with the explanations. As can be seen form [MN908947](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/MN908947), the virus [mRNA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RNA) contains "head" (265 nucleotides), "tail" (229 nucleotides) and [translated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_(biology)) parts with some non-translated parts between them. So, we have 10 genes, named orf1ab, S, ORF3a, E, M, ORF6, ORF7a, ORF8, N, ORF10 in [the link](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/MN908947) above.
It comes out we could use [codon usage bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codon_usage_bias) as the picture of frequency codon (=nucleotide triples) usage is very impressive, e.g. for `orf1ab`:
[image]
or for `S` (looks very similar):
[image]
and for `N` (looks different):
[image]
More precisely, here's the table of normed [covariance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance) of the codon usage distributions:

```
       orf1ab S      ORF3a  E      M      ORF6   ORF7a  ORF8   N      ORF10 
orf1ab 1.0000 0.9243 0.7458 0.4237 0.4813 0.5143 0.6391 0.6897 0.5035 0.3201
S      0.9243 1.0000 0.7077 0.3834 0.4596 0.5266 0.6513 0.6451 0.5371 0.3519
ORF3a  0.7458 0.7077 1.0000 0.4683 0.5483 0.4119 0.5713 0.5957 0.3464 0.2862
E      0.4237 0.3834 0.4683 1.0000 0.2966 0.2057 0.4727 0.2994 0.0318 0.2621
M      0.4813 0.4596 0.5483 0.2966 1.0000 0.2495 0.3799 0.3432 0.2975 0.1776
ORF6   0.5143 0.5266 0.4119 0.2057 0.2495 1.0000 0.3737 0.3459 0.1980 0.3125
ORF7a  0.6391 0.6513 0.5713 0.4727 0.3799 0.3737 1.0000 0.5232 0.3223 0.2362
ORF8   0.6897 0.6451 0.5957 0.2994 0.3432 0.3459 0.5232 1.0000 0.2049 0.0902
N      0.5035 0.5371 0.3464 0.0318 0.2975 0.1980 0.3223 0.2049 1.0000 -0.0203
ORF10  0.3201 0.3519 0.2862 0.2621 0.1776 0.3125 0.2362 0.0902 -0.0203 1.0000
```

So we want to compress these genes. Here's the comparison of compression approaches:

```
         arithm  .lzma    .xz   zlib  a.ovh    len
0:orf1ab 4925.7   5261   5308   5083   86.5   7097
1:S       879.5   1047   1092    940   59.1   1274
2:ORF3a   191.4    276    324    237   37.4    276
3:E        47.8    100    132     84   18.6     76
4:M       155.4    232    280    200   35.1    223
5:ORF6     36.9     86    120     70   15.4     62
6:ORF7a    81.2    143    184    124   25.2    122
7:ORF8     80.2    144    184    122   24.2    122
8:N       289.9    393    440    338   44.1    420
9:ORF10    22.5     64     96     47   11.6     39
```

where `arithm` is arithmetical encoding and `a.ovh` is frequences compressed with fibonacci (+1 ending bit for each) -- the arithmetical encoding overhead.
We see the comparison makes zlib a perfect candidate, as even if we compress all with arithmetical encoding, we would have left something like 193 bytes for writing the decoding overhead (versus zlib), which is highly unlikely to fit in there.

Answering on [stux](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95705/stux)'s comments:

> However it looks like you need auxiliary tables to do so?

Almost no. I can number out nucleotide triplets just like numbers at base \$4\$ of length \$3\$. `itertools.product` does the job well. But yes, we have to know what nucleotides do encode peptid amino-acids and which do not, for this we need [the first link](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/MN908947).

However, it's rather tricky to get the right sequence for `orf1ab` because of it's code consists of \$2\$ overlapping sequences, which is rather rare in the real world, IMHO. They do overlap on the nucleotide at position \$13468\$ (see `join(266..13468,13468..21555)` in the above link), so we double this nucleotide, compress, and then cut it out after de-compression (with `cut_out`).

Then we compress joined sequences of triplets (not separately because orf1ab+S is rather large compared to other parts and the encoding table (frequences) will not differ much for orf1ab+S compared to all peptid-coding parts joined). Also we compress the non-peptid-encoding parts because we also need them in the output. Joined too.

Then we have to `cut` both sequences into apropriate pieces (pieces lengths are `genes_len` and `rest_len`) and interleave (with `for i,j in zip(cut(...,rest_len),cut(...,genes_len))`). \$269\$ is compressed non-peptid-encoding nucleotides length and \$6985\$ is compressed triplets length.

Looking back at the comments it's left only to explain how `cut` works. The python `reduce` function takes \$3\$ argumets: function(accumulator,item), the sequence and the optional accumulator initial value. Then accumulator on the next step = function(accumulator on the previous step,item from sequence). In other words, `reduce` feeds the sequence into the function and returns the accumulator when the sequence runs out. E.g. a way to replace `math.prod`: `lambda z:reduce(lambda x,y:x*y,z,1)`.

So the accumulator in this particular case is chosen to contain [the sequence to cut,array ot already cut pieces] and `acc[0]` is the sequence to cut, `acc[1]` is already cut pieces, so `acc[0][n:],acc[1]+[acc[0][:n]]` makes perfect sense now, doesn't it? And we need only the `reduce` return value at index \$1\$ (i.e. the pieces sequence).

Did I answer all the questions?)

Comment: It's impressive that you managed to compress the original file down to 6985 bytes! However it looks like you need auxiliary tables to do so? I'm guessing that's what the other non-source numbers are for?  A bit of this explanation goes over my head as it seems that certain steps may be missing some explanation for those not familiar with your work... Maybe I can form more explicit clarification questions below.

Comment: Some questions: 1. If I understand correctly, decode.py produced the input file f, can you provide a copy of that?  2. I'm somewhat of a python newbie, can you explain a little more what the code itself does (such as a commented copy)? 3. It seems like you chose zlib to compress the nucleoties? But clearly that's not all you did and I don't see where the code decompresses with zlib.  Any further clarification would be most appreciated!

Comment: Sorry I just answered my question #1 a little late, I just noticed that the google drive link has your other sources. I'll comb through those when I get the chance and try to learn more.Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for the comment spam, but after several readings I think I understand your source better: 161 is the first snippet, 287 is the compressed size of D(d[:x]), which is the 2nd snippet, but what is the 269 for? All I understand is that it's a second header in the payload.

Comment: Your questions are very welcome. Please see the edits in the tail of the answer.

Comment: I'm sorry for the late reply.  Real life and all that. I think the edits do clarify several things.  I'll see if more questions come up when i sit down and study it again :)
Also, I noticed that your total byte count went down :) I was thinking that you might be able to move the 2nd and 3rd import statements into the compressed segment if eval() allows it. Might save some extra bytes!

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 118 + 1 + 7313 = 7432 bytes

Saved 10 bytes thanks to [ovs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64121/ovs)!!!

```python
import zlib
j=int.from_bytes(zlib.decompress(open('z','rb').read()),'big')
s=""
while j:s="UACG"[j&3]+s;j>>=2
print(s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZX13v9W20vX/@RQOJbSgWLZkS0mAAAktlNAhVFV67/WrP@9aY3mfk/vyu/eknT3bkkZr1lS//PT24Yvn4/89evbyxeu33Ys3P7x4o958evO2PNu75@PH3B183alHz1@@e6vePnrRHe4@79m3/VcO/zR0HxL/7Sri89NH8YfHhx49f6vq6xfP7sVPb8ubvfy3Kpf04tnL1@XNm70vXpbne/d83vPzntdxzz71uoS8d9@@n/fERw/wBW8O7djxw4eHj56W7vGv@IerR4@f3HHr8U/jnQNvfnt8@PCh4YeXr/ENe9/s@7//69ufX7vZ@dQN2c9d9TZ2PvRzF4Y4dUbrqRt0b7tkYt91H9VBpW4p/DmqfsTPHxYJGjJ641Jng0mdMdPYmZpKV43BJ/vQd73tx24IQ@k6pf49@2e6oNRflLN/lTFAxuCH0PVhcN1g8CHdz7mzOuOTJtuud1PoxgE/un371d5dSn27qPDz8fC4yRghw/TJdsHih86670Iepi6HyXVTKnOX0mw6P@DfdX8o@fOTevhUqbfqpybDQMaY8Z34ddPNwfYdhMUuz9Hhkz50zs22M3HEcxzCJz//c1t2RL37@9cmw0JGill3Ouixy2OYOu9H/F3FJ2f87MZa@66m2XE/5M@o3n1TR5T62GRMfI464ldLzp3WfAQ9Vi4jdyVSWgr4RzumrjsyH@a5HHlKOar83mTMPJceG5ZHnGPQdujqGE2XfS2dyaPr0jzPHU6az/EYT3GJj3LOqQ8HHjYZDjJyxLcP/WigC2bsfB59FwoexmtTOztZ2zmjK2Tc6syPx5XHQi5cu7rRDw8Z0eXa1bm6bp4GPEeaatf7pLuSe92NcYDy1bHtx/sd6gX/@tse5ZqMABlVz303aYtfncuA3S3Y2FHnrgaPrTDYGV9zhIyX4XrbV5W39DRChhsm3cV56LvRuxHfiWOFNI3dNa7LLoxdX3FgnQqq84uIU2pLRpKznQsEYetirtD6ZDQUAlsRJ55L7qkflmv5rj4odfvo3xd4Ln/faDIy99QP2L8eyx6nKUHbBt457Icz89hNNSVoykAZv6g901O1B4/w5oX6trfJKJRRQ@jKiIua@DC64JOh4pLVMs3d7K3pks5z07EP6g1@Pvh0ZbOWyrs/hxm3dfJYixmgCzimPgAPajH4D2GuuH116LoP6sIjdewAJZ08g3v3Q7v6kBEiNMsG3Lna41xCAVZMCZc3hpHHWjNVmfpx6V95lKff1KzUkSNNBvFj6F3u0phNVywewc/GdNPkc@c0Nqrq4rs@Wt@tF@bPqrAzSt1sMogfLmpcT4tHLtph7XXM2IUSsTQNlRucXGO9uXOHPrW/aTKIH2XGhpkB@5d0j92dXO1Cgqb0ETfH2z53ecAlgIxjD9TWn@NNBvEjE66AFxlbh3MJkSo6AlRjb3HAGf/Oe0sdU1/Urg/y@Ys4n2tNBvGjzjF1OuKqDFMcO12hHy4ACmLETRtyX7o44OJxLTt@UqIfROerTQbxY4oTtRPfORQCM3QDH4J@pB5r0dbj1Cogunvy9PZFdfZMW8q9v5oM4ge2I3Vugi7EGQDgTHZdmKDwZbY4sBlXJUUDLPz2VZ1URkzDHfw802QQP6zD2mvPe0uFKEPC7pZiePtyZ0ZAaawZZ3tDqevUDNnQXzfnQvyAguNsh7FgK3Blk8GCUl8SsD5gfSPO1pYEHdvzWQEM1VnK2KnurjKIHxOMFHR9gEJU13cmASt0rRraBsAfxwE/jMd@3D914UATocadZpVB/LDJBcgA3iSYmg7/1HfeAU/zBEyZCU5JV@jHbXVh1Y3u1fXNWogfNVA1IpYxVO6uwTLKWIApRPNskoehgsLjbA@oX76KjN@36angRwVoz7CJnZ6h4fgMTlTjcGaP07AAw85aXJ9OPXzZtuPTmWvnr64yiB@jmDgtsInTGAFpXfTVQ@UK1pKAHzUQ1w@/fYXPuz00l183@KGJHzBsBkCOL7Z58DCdwHVrB9zbhDtkY4DK5QT8oG7c2XfoxdWD6sGtzVoGwY9@HqAVUMfCI@yHhGOKMLX497g@BrvVj4V37vWyoX83fW8yiB/JE0pHgPs44usCbZqzeCzvaQBLsTAVPe/cnjEAjB/i44@3ySB@hDTZrngyBp8LuAO2ojichk4Bm2K5z2HgnhZsRPuzW5052GQQP@YEpuNnIGAOsFZ5mLEpxulurjjlCBzEdYDcTo71pfpkRMqN9TmIH30dB4IINhZmBWuBkTERam4s7Ms4A5IKngvPMaz78dc4b61F@EcQLjXh4xmQ1xNESsT2TBHrA5vDxZuI66BgWYSEJz/9rU6sMogfg/FxwXBgAe7@hNuaNRY08C5nbBoWBP3vwMJmcCioWHdd7dg8B/GjpJFa5CxsGp7DFtyvEAb8owOaF49jGkFiF/14gfuqdj@8qR4eXmUQP6qDLQkAkA7m14OUYSeHhAX5gciaR2BQxbXs1Dcu5LP6mX@ZNs9B/MA3gckFcK8ehAW3D5BuLKAR9GPAVuDj2hXqx33YqHJA/XVRYTc2MgQ/Jugp1IkUGXodZgODAu2jVSGdywNUjtyhvl7VdLt9GYgfuU@RRgYPX0cwkcB7OwaYlt4QHwOWNpfVZmv5eZLq3mQQP/wIlQbzq1wQNoWsdNb4O68DLxIIwVwcz/ZxOUKL@0rEfF9lZMGxSOSBXnszWpgFD5s9Y4tdxL0dPA5M@9QTx/DHgjjgf/u21iL8YwCuZw2m7zWAK83YiuohLSdoeNA05qGEtpbfFznb9oP4YQL5R5qpHx42ntetUOu9ASDWKQZgIYhud0adffdim8H9oVF@cssZdq54XLx@wod88kBFD7k55QTdhbIO00T8eLpNwPWfUpOhFz0lJZxwOFpDwyOw0wxAZ2vA5GocgI/TTA7T@yfE5WNfr9xQu6b1OQbhpxO4eYA@FY@16xhhs3sA@VCwR6MzvnOga5DxbOsx3Gn1W5NB/LBxpscBNchTDrTP0IpxpsaCBwHvY5cy6EV36yVP5t5J9e7AL@rJZj@IH7PYRQ/EBOSVbvJ4eCgavh0OCfQfqwJWYy0v5Qke7ZK/fN3IEP7hsKcwhrYDXIJWeguLF6By2eIRwgjHpg@R/PTp6au/juoeOP@TbedC/LD05/wEYgyvDYoWYfdzjREUyAZc6ABNqaCO3c396kIDVKrrpSaD@AHHByYAdBCbwm@fsLTReQeaaKgzM435LHxMvb0NB8rBs3zxRb1pMpzIgKXueW@rBu0Ck@vBpXAk0cIfwbWFNR7q2PT0WjuYgzvWtRA/fCr8zok/sH@RfB2giCtIrug0vmEIZhAZD7GXe9SFS7gy@481GcQPnAEoU7aJ6IzrRgIGXgcUdaAjxcCYJ@sXfnpbdUWt9q7JIH6YiLtv@cjgX1hBIgOAOQee4rY6h6MebIWO/f34zsF38mmYul27VxlJ/H0g9zgEXJWADcjJ8O88rxug0QywPr4AH7uPO8TAnMf/y7Fh8xzEj0jUcDZ6/L4mwpOkWnjLk4mglRkbBa@Ra8GdP0Yp/2R15@FGBvHDO3qTPcikHXDF5wJANA4IXyp8iWHGJeiroYzj6ugl9V3TEYPhP9pkED/qBIAZq4NyZ0CenhKew9HYTXAjXA9AnILhvaV3vfnz@MIPzd3nWkgb7DRPIC19D/MEqzJlkIWh4vLi2WA1U6Z@hGvv@elncD0uAUyaDOIHcBzcq0JZ5wITYOaIm1Nxl10e6EEAg8IkfP0UkfikOvISQq6vfN0QP4rBr2IFsCoEEVfBg4DjOBLiwVxwwMCxKj5hIx9nIeunF02G4AfZo7fQTsjADwNUdBPuy8h9jgPuXBnIHa40DqVUf3RLxwzxoxRoxZQBP6kHgfAjGHNyEBToTVY4uIRL2mwCWVYHVn@qybASQ8E59gkOqi0j@CxDTJOf4TwUA/M04QrGmb7HIXzwLhztRx/VCWxu8z3Mgh@FZhXmPeeKtbuRmAxfXQ8QVGbgdK0gZd1NsfZ7D0HPPm5bC/EjkB3j/kM/GE6KZnEZGBPhtSeuwz6IL/aPWviDOnhgl3rfZBA/BkAgiB1c294CwpyjT1igd2GEEcW9hUcVQIu6nerrNh1Tn5oM4gc4MAiHn@gYYnfBkGnCwZirxrNllwwxhc@x83T5Au0q@5b4VJNB/AgjnKSJ3kXkVcEHwQY9HGUXoFkxgwakSbi2CsId/J/q6rb9iOJXAj@qw5WdHB18Te6QKvwAGhko28S4Q1niQQ9PHsWK3rxT176tMogfIMI41r4HkMN5h8Uj5SX1yCT@FfQfGgjO2t3lnjY0ZWypyRD86EmeelgySwYwFUCHztNEe9vTjYCf2Cfux980Cs//UfXKP4cebGQIflA7ccUnKlUPFwCOZHbwBLGgRCe@Eoh458hw/1C/0sgde3GnNBnEjzIOmtQDpmgGiAwOMBisxtkmqBfoOyNfmvvxI9nH3mU1X7r2HJb4Uajr3gLMev5@IoHwpPu@h7QIPgItdkZw/Thc/v/hMFb4B4Mm1jjSfRwhjPBE1EjcU1yCCTQ7Tr2c7ZXFSsFCbJNB/LAzrkolDyqZMceRoYzQAwbjzIjdzNuELeuuT8v3w@P/BB8kNxnEDzdyxdYzVoqdMT6R5MN/gcGbaCDggDPa1qkvu5X68bSE69TzzXOI/9IvGGSAQTC6w2y4C5FuOvx3cFZcxlEvvBDcYw/sy87D/26thfiBS4Vl4Krxx0SPQ4Jq4iIC1mCJiQLgyacWF/vq35dkVz40GcSP5AY4gbowpjQAfhy@3dFvmGpPBoCd0Wagn81j/RlOxxJ23NdkED8GxlAML03PSJlEuZIGQQeBhjdUANEAODzHgacnHy/0hbzs7txkCP/wwN9KywROBoY4gfOHwQ1L@DAPwEdTFzwlijbl8BcanlovNrsPnfPA8GkGDyp0RicH/yyAi5Enw@P2MGMdAPDogyNi9ek9hCaD@DF6uh0WPyZ@PBVgcu5heeGjzXCmIu0FqLfEPYtafY/NuQj/MIyqBxqqLMG6kUcyw48a8XcB1g7oQj39c4nPDXA@hm0yBD8AVVgQds0xaAJapBmHxIIKaIPW0JSoGce9pT7O1PIP6vnDbTKyPAcWmyesIAyj6EImIYXciQFe2hc3cC1/BvEFgezvwzYZReJB2uFD8AlrBBybzEiScFw4V904GhLuirt/X7binNp/RF0eL2xkED/6gJtpemz/NDBnkXntLXyxYSzkNYCOPPcSy/lDRbVEpS5tnmOS@McIwJ16@nMaLvnAvEDRjtFYHnqBT5Pp80LG/SMX1c8fVTO5TYbEP8ZMN5Y8IfNhAOJwWDLgeE7MnSRx2AWDTmAzHqgGAbuaDOLHqKFeKcFRKCN0fSY/jYyEgKlD7mzBtTVc5k4LYxB2efvDLXWxyZD8Cz3HmLRl0BAsYjKw2YzWTzOwDd4x9nlmDEWQ41Q9dxLP8u/jky2GMhnhMJaxdFhDXSQ@QEhnPBQUxuAbsEfeCIe5x/zNYQbZ1emt/SB@uIrfh12DdQMNwxMVwGACDNoMZlYm3Lk86oWvn3kj1voO7txGhuAHo7fWwXCXVKFtlswsglyPaYLW2wACUcU2fLixc9nO3yPVvsmYxUbhaRNJarVgEfgkLzsskykVW2FJsgJczxaT/v3RhRfnmRrrmwyJn9IY1IyNrWOir9JrxrZgwuvAtYAGJIMFdZfFd9mB/7/YTQRpMogfgb6Hr2SlwTKj5mhgYWV7j0uAJwBCmeiX5/j18i5x@LfpGPEDlwwXNTFsUXAQPuYJEIZnSzMUfiJ3tpJbU6@@6tWXeqouNQ4zRYk54kFxSxiUx68WmnDtJt5DrMXiQvA6wK887CU7lwFku/@5r1reYxL/heE4W0dGX3A3ksbvlwEYC4MA/AjMVxbsUfdV3fttMdp7tvHCKYuu41jhtWWsCqbFCj0rOJdBA5NBdKE4ERvVaZ7s1ds7z79gxvPL5SaD@GEqIwXw8MFPofATwzIpZE1upBlexlEzEdFdEAOTHpNjnlVH1@eQ@KmDuwQ/COoFr4cUCA6ZBasamEoxGfs8EFi6Fg0CDnZAotU3nfuFO2SGPrD2AjaoBzoKFegVAmgRCA68cJ1s0zEC8wX1x7DZj1lLHBe7kB24pTbGM/cKmz0CNXyCo1cckASUnjb7qly270s059AqQ/IvZsauDbBkgWHBUMB@NGCUjhD4R4LGujmTO3x@vVg5c@TT1rnMxI9@gDGoBd8EjwsbQJFwWAKAyPcM1BfueG1rGf78vGjp3lUG8SNlMPJ@BmlJdOvh/znuJAAxwnWZIkNdeVjjUurxqXPqN/VEPdvfZAj/gDcFwMAXO8MAxugk6QBeCK5JhY/YFOxM92cPERd2CpninjQZxA9sAD7pYsSqMpN0dB4iQHViOjwl3Bwoifj7jVfS6l47u66F@JEKnsMHW4B7sLwgzI7uMXgy04x2jrQcmXGYXt09zUCyugO38v4qQ@KnPb/OO9A/hi16Ul7Y6JEBGubJoS44nFU/9qgf1c6bu7edi@BHD0o4Oxil5AC9Lk@0L4CwibwGxzIzYifnIlctTqqKO9VkCH4Y2PhEQ19H6JixeoJPiN2dM2xfytk131Se4/Rf6tGFb0e2PQfxox/nYdHTMULrI9300TKlk6E4AXQeTq6LS66Al98eEBayyiB@gHsVYtC4SBsrDFvN08gE7ADroxkLdmue8PWRWyotrLvJIH54SMIywDXSEl7DPR/hpuL2wZhH2BZGIJZ7G8hyD7V4bpNB/JgNtNnBD2HeOSwxWHj5mpFDHOs444QKLHr3Vi3JJF669GbNac3EjzREsEFGBYaRz0EbDxDgieKAc8/t8S2e/GLnLjzJHyAgMHQ/tPS@@LcWfL2nebf44qItzeTAWHB0eEqcFYgd9mPnTan@uHkH2vH29LoWJ/lbEkFQEZiRHisYeVGnAhLXazh1MZBpMfPQ7RY2ONNlqFv@rSN@@KxhmSIEuZCYPALdT2OhtQdjtlDebuyHJS8GKbekWuGe6htfd8QPzSAc7kbFsjUsXvQT1QWYEmHxbNGMBGbaqGN3VMvvM@uwrkX4R4KH7gElgG/y2SmA5FuguS@wF3DvGGfqZ4mN/0EqdPU//pyzwmFADMIANyxqA8ONK9yNpvgOPh03CihgWJbSiTcHg7/kgc60ugs3SUza4PQYzAozQEcHZlCLY5gP9gVciklZTR074SSiLQHUjY/sJP4Bhx8OLdcSQIclyWkraLMr1jCRib/rpe7ivfrjjBp33oOqQ9la3YUT/yVK9IVFDwFbp9MolgZ3H2DIo8Z/na3ET/dSRZ068xgnvKfZSif5lxFqkIUx9DnhgjBvSt5bKzc7Adb6lHj367YIyo3NWiT/YiaYloxzjM4GOiCMtpGUZRx1YHY39djYLj9bIsnfW/VGkyH1H06qcSopAp6oMiNfNEw4bitMS6bFG/2af6nqYsurrzIkf8s8iWXG2jl4y1PAw2uGk3AahDAAfslG8BS7@eXxDRGwiW054ocrusKBA2JGK1UcLDZIWMvo8Mm5J7HrF0x@uGYK/nq5e/McxI/UM16Cq9MVv9xREP/YMxSE21p7PODIaBv29EZHgiwBenX4RJMh@ReysBTASicDmNAs1kgG26P1zJA2Tj7T6@zO/aQeLYlC9XX/Jgbre4mvY@vmwfEc4ZHCMYZWaFhIk0FNC/xGPNuiH69bWusc/9L0wwv/gIHG2WLnvWXVQmYi3Ws67JqECkYmw29s5/L0juj6P5tz8RL/GGAHNAOE2TAz1cN307YnPgKdpwIG3DNs3V06sKVizzc22xM/fAATBmyyQAp8xXqQMl8gcvaJZg/KOrq58Y9z6iYdB1H5JmOJn0Kvw4Qri2WA6dse/n6BVekr/tFZ/FdvU@P8d@79tcDY1lqIH5KwChV7WpmqGXpwXHB23JwZaJT8yB0HmHU/JYl/7D3F0OPh16sM4R@hwPkyMAGZWYY6k5QROiYGlQcLUztXLTVXf7ajebh799ZzzOLPsRZoBOjMLoKvj2DdvkKuIxcQsgfrnRZ/7uNictXrQ99aDZp3ErsAyY8anwTiwbnUOGpPOxcI6ZlZtsRMQvcxL5//bz7KL/lbXAs9MozO6BJ8DfpRuDQmgbjWAUZ0EkwGlopuXFBnr6oLdZURpEYRBjZMJoKGGqzKs7ipaqbIGQSMjgnVFqf7myUTvyj14xMASZNB/Jjp@cyAcxzEDFBluL3OMy4eE@NiWgD9eA7BnpfY12/hE9lDk0H8mPhJkFh854j7UhhUHgxcRBAov@idTuTaD14qUg8Y7fNyY5oM4sfEuiZy5i6wFNENsEyxD8z2OYakwMzgHELHHin1hpFPpR7Rzv3TZBA/@jjixmdcVNhbJgYdiwFxEFMPP7EG4DS8ee5pq8k5oCQScr3JIH5MttDempk1JwAADS/EaKbVmJTVs5uX0HdX1J2T106xPEiysDt/aGV9EodJ2HmcEW4OiO6gGcZk0sHA0wPxZ/GWYc3Efd74uz9O6sDJbfY2SPxU8qbFEiaA8LMDDfAZJC47z9o2ELXihTu8vHsZmnpsqXlYY31hkJoJqFLP7I8bNSihmRm8YViLNXmph65PBNWuGfzv4JVv1KGVawepH@P2AyVG0AZwwBBB8sda4FsRmPMM1XeLzV6A8NqR/3CHIPVjCeAwMeMaZgjSiaTdAQ80s3I9H8HGJFj46J4wdsGAW6sMyb@wKNHiGaCxE2zUiFOOA0XCFcRKGf8jKna/H72Xvj9JDYE2z0H88JYRzzyx6Az6MRPMhgjlng0pUAa8WqyXz3EHFvfbvQNSBLLy0yD@S/RMweP3E4MPheg1R8J8BX0J9AOyKWZTk8fw@AO14ZbByblAs9zAlBgzZHA9QpdZzMYaNZCbkrA@8QkZDP5F7V8kpVWGF3uLb7f07Ud4MbhpLGazMI74BgO3Cqc8lUniQReh7ueNFH8Mz2OTIfWnA5zokbkFUCk8zDiB@Hi6HZUlFLjcgLVBzvZ3Jj3v71sqHpqIKOWFMLeB5gXODz1saNzQw@Z6C6UPFbbOjBNV7Cc8yHN1tZPU1vFHTUYSGbhUUHocS6E/W@Hu4DEmbil5GgyYS8MmpPRC4THu7908hrCPSGcQZBebaQrDfcQReJWZ3A6EzTGasVjbPyT/K4n19KzJIHpEWjQJ/QKsJpYIMWUJS1kSpBmiAda8MCkWoIh9ObFhY4HoMYTgWS83kxsDCSuD4gwJhQq98hmargO9Wx6pWct5N1sapXpdAz61ZhAssAoFxIYVVCyMG/BEEIIfjNC/WqtQJgmRtQh91EvEkdnKzA3IjGwlJl2ppZpogFuMOw287q7cXL7/7H9ubRT2wdQbdIAXFnjmDK5dTaBCxYPqlZ4rnZndbwUGT/6bBYpEj4GlYdXD6bBwZLo5aaHnGbeQqhdLDxuYStftlZJRmMhDd8RkNhmSfRks8@b4uBkySUNmtoHlowYKOrPuJ41SeX6bSnpK8sBfN5XnUarHeuxpZX1kZLYhjyNMnaO3P2sW1gZyAluaih1R/aklXHi3yZgkC8RkRc/KDTLLwKh2muCemqnwGjHCDEmQcfT@2yskD7tO4Hi@rmsR74XR55ElzcHzMDM5uiH7ZhgxzCGD@y/VuEck8LlLcslrNW6U6vUJmJsjyA7cL0Y@wdY9vbNcLB1KYoBvFSRQ9V03WIHSn1grSKKghwHwzgwzYOk4g4k1PhMuPVxWkOwB19AXicKodwu3tBJ0WNcSRMdYP0jmEJjnHCsgNWFZ3ZhZQsnS8ZQYMbhCZ7/SLhwyrBtvMggfMUpsH/uhmT@apNQA7AXmATuTUxHvVu7cA@G2Z/6rY@K9JGbEp5FKwrSxSeDGSdPzwCWYLWN4DNhDxrXfaemeKnfz3ecPq4wsVRfkHCXC72F6YZ4C3FkHj7ByZxwuEaviGYX5dUkQnpIHuf13kyHZF0tOj13sJrZETAUrSIygWNYFRCbIQ2B0vRB4yNPV9b@2rYX4YQO2P7BMcbSV1hYXpAR6eANL0h3ubZ@BS92/W8Vnl3DAr39oxfxiKUfyLag5GHHFLohbDapQeoAI@K/kpbCnvxt1ZLdyD4Cn02n1/EGTIexjgPc3gfLgRHFzjJNNIW@fmEUewaRgrxhROvj0PV3S90sB6Y9NxiCssI9MPYODzcLB9Mgof0@ez8g/y64CKyUfiMm/v0DqpvIrifcigeS5sFyMu8uies8ISj943BybAI3gl3gOrTZlG1uMPxmp/AJh0szbDIUlIymKy894DPN0gbmcMS0e0DnSOTXfUp831jYRPzTgvKsxWPg9IKGJ91zDkYHZxmYDDkACsjCH882N26fM@Y9rlUGS6IeBDDiYklmYaREAx9PEylgb6ejjKb1UF55fKKWKS29Sk0H8GMeQlnBYnQHuoD54eFJJQBBAxLpCDMJaRto5MS/Pr17dYFAS74Vw5QHP@KRnztFKXnuEhkPaHHFz4FjAZONg@yyBwtuS5G8yvGCy4VZEQ1/I0XUAfzIRN60wWEAaP4XkxXtRHx/yYOE/vHm8ypDoR2HkeMAmDgPYx5QmclKwAHiKMwsLefJYafdcxX07jj0FpaszzvmPJkO8lwE4FgNUo5bI2AsLry2cQe@wvp6V@MOMpXWt8Ow1lKNXv67Vp4n4kTM@mSP8xpjA3lJhTVCpLORgtrLCM801rZ766VbUd3izH1K9nqHNXmiGhUJkJubA6HBWPXAa5IpRGNEx6Hcx6lOLTK8yylLpFHE4uDTasRqAzTBgl6xuySx06BmfgiDg6XvJRC2pgsd7mgzhHywZgY1mNrvS@4uMM7KA3hGSLMiaF/3Y9@uyjntnbqjy0/ocuV86vfDwLCAeQLC7eWSDVjUERHyyJ/Gew9rpdWD3Gxhd0tTPzd5mwY8AtCtzYi8SgZyFk3nmVvQ8ppFRWS/VMMuf/f/lDpn4ESeW0JBQh5HXvod5mjUQLbH2BN48QEQyr7hvPBX7aknitsxrXvADnuyoe7bAkBKOcJjHPjO4bHjAkMb6HVZaa6nq69XOv3C655oMiZ7WwDp5hrFnsmRW4HgGD8cRpzFINTorlrt7tE7HVFHfxz1bEbZM/ChVs8kLH7LMjxkGMVNiKaxJbDsDiwhAFtmP7zfUhfdSp7BrI0Pwg/bFk2CXwlwfqz6TYQ8cwA1cig4iS5U6CeDulO63/Nuxtfo0S/WpZ/4t4tvjUCbmn4GiHk9U5sxORxxYcEtm/oBUBu5bEmzrcwj/YHQdRhcAoBnfm7CC5MnZWWBgCCyDkezczVa2rnZe@LtfO6yy8A8HcjEm3rQIR8d4xvZJgbz2lsFGKGuSrIcQ3NM7JbR9cq1QzFJ9OtNPggMLhScHZLuX5SWzRdSLGa1h8UwlBHvsssTFN2uR7G3PKBbjFePcs72JDrOfGaanN0MIKxosqeslxr/rKhCEhvtAkyHuC3YFlhpq3jumtRj57KWBjx14I/fIMHi46Prd43TTT@lN1jSL/0KFmAxpOfsKgX0anwSj1CPI71joFrJDqFPv81pIfxsQdLbJKMLpMuu8WZYUQbOjhcZG5n4GCROxJDcxSCVdOIut3LV9P6p0RmZLAgaazcw8LA1MbWBfEHu@JpYJjCyk7pgePN4KYZ9G9/SH1sQn/APuwWxxtmUkkGusZdK1pxvBykCgohtZcfU7Ky5mqe3b9hyF@JE13DCYJzCogZXqrCPLmVWOQSqtC@NewuleYT92mbXSepUh1R@WVbNUEj2DIhRmfPqJDGrqCdGwW9VX4JjdXuO4qegto3Q1sprIAtcLKFRnWGCTEqimh/WC9kxs6ttkXl//IeqKrWyZ12LkbGHYegsnuNCgWEa145ipbYbrY/UTmyg6UI5HkiJQu86T/jcZVqK4nhekMmw7MNHgJZzO5N6kGVGdmUlqmcZP8vMKtrX/ucmQ6KllB5KFPhVW8fSMQ@e5Sn8j@3FYLWVd36q11aYzaX0O6b5llM4VlkzRwM6eH6J3OLDQIbN9Nmm7Zht6mrnuPuh/i7AVyb6MdKGYtA6saQmZDNE6TXcfu@uqYcCe9uXtrZXPbauWKtI9N7L4puCqGFYHQXcrOw3wMOywmkIZWZUjFax3JdJ464Pa81idbNGxQvxwHrZhZhB9cmAuoC@Q1rN4qrKkjpoyGDmXb9/lAf6QBMqKY0W651jFkyvcH2PFVgLHEmvyDS9eoaebPDtnr@Ojf@1@s1Nd@5Op09Y5W5J0EmtSMShVyTRxI8vmWQ4UmeubDLvEbRLfNP@u7JulC/ixXZ8jy57iqmTmeBOrAAMdFjitvgP5h88LlaUDbreiUktg6uIqg/hRac4CGyuzdjCYBUjiR/a5025p6QDpBU/3MFxAorvn@7Zzke5bj69zcWZNIWzrwMqNfmJ9cGCikuUpaWIV26cvvPw71mvbZNR@6cADfrDdaxgAwjBRrNgEV0yebWTsww22UD@OfN6/47mUbg1MzTcZWngy2KO1llQWZ6CtnAYHAgw92wxndgMxezvqq7fWCsWX79bsbR1kTzVLveguaXYjW1ya2YB1AwbZpVXZsiAZPhjr8IFN90@fkYA0GVL9YcjHimE7Q9Cs7gZjZmTXW@xC76C7fpAK@F/VeerYl6WFpVXAV@KHBi3DtzNc4AIwqxAGWdpUE/4xFk44GP1S6bRjc7q3NvthBdcH1lJjQXa0xI@ZzTAjXTMGigxL2Oc6S/ecuvyP@np63nNTnVh95CrxD2txVVhbAGrPnn12vJPeTqVOME8DO73kOe68uPVYSk9hKn9euXYlfkxBMie4aVI3VSZ8e7CsC6hstYhkJzM5zGPA@mEPBvHm3j9P1J7GYapETyMuSJ4MK/JwhI7hEPBLaBZLFyMrvpObFl3/a9PXeE21Kukq2RcwO9IuhvRYTMNY7MQWh8KCz@JwtjYyQo9Lv1edOtaKx9aIdJXoKdOZ8OjZ8s/2QbqqJeAK1hHXeJp4q6e@VaCp61LtZKtaMzg1SryQPeojqFh07JfN4DzGssQQH4Wpxccj413d/mNLQd5f507cd1v3hfgxRqGVLLFiOaFLji10weNE@TC99OKxc/Y3MMtdrXV@253L0m1KHWPtThzogQXox6grS9k0MRZ2Sw9lw9cfSzncVganSvVHhvMKAwFn1MJWDibQGWUV2wj10hNo1MxClY5VNOX1LnilO0@oA2uGrwr/KLijA5OjAT4oO6sB7hMrhthnGYlQk5MuT5bRnhbCDhh6uMjQMv1jNLjdIzAeAMA@MwtLUzIfZpRr7w1r0CHDvOvV1XeMFrxh6eeOJkNLVgw0Y2B6Epx/5odArRhXyRwwkbIdmZcCl/r@7172iaufDTb18qP1OcR/qdiwUtmGZOEUTxkPPzNo0juc0MjoKv7rpnv/GeuUhC03Ga36NDCdj1@NzERLkWRh4TovUraWgTOQoaX6lBGy93D5725kSPecC6wLj5x2EWjToFmGBePwVwP7r0BuCjaFldZ4hF33WZrz98ONDOmeo6OAs624vLqVq@PegaQmMH3rWdHLavTVvlx7BiIE@n@4yZgk1gcLGQsIhDbQyUT@Fg17mzMb5xLL6z0zfBLAWf/sahk@LdM/HAuTK6vvepwmAIMNOJZ2boZvmj1@aNf8qE9qfvLxP36llukf/QDVcLOT3ptKP4rJASMVmAHQyIBOqs3fJ8FNp@/9qszZVYaXrjVjWCrNJlF6pAa8UIsbMYFfVSBtFwZmov/@c32C6TaJbpMRJCYNm5b7FGg1@cXwWuxIRtl7rkpjo@gCLJwOzv7lfH/7WgQ/OEwlc0TMxI69eQR2zhxvMbF53RFoCzBmkRHUm0tv1bN922QQP8wMY@oKC8cGWTvtC6zBMo5DM9ZXpDMSav56MGfV/@ypVI8lXFSvJ4Y9J0bbqPCMIlsNXXfsQ3dDWPjpg@ePGNq6KMWBTUaR7H6UysrIiis2MyfmthJLLhngJZWY7BKjP/KF0D6Li1vuNhnCPzRsSdHgb4bNFHMYcWm8p6sP12VmUsUYxqRfMWzx4fNv4B/xFTzcH9rgDuGW8giSPDe0CCCTmp3SQm4SWwWsVBfuxFP8ywjua7CZX26vMrTEpNn1x/EWPX2xXAzpC5UkkfhnaM88D1t8TPyog39@2N1kLNXrnrjO6C0bgCvzJGHmcBmW5oy@Zy5zZPW6utFqm8eDXt3RTcYotpL9gtNM7ymzZJVzMqQHyMLBGh0T5HXxCevbhRXufuXWim8t0z8KG7Q0y5IMA3PZFM3xSZp1NDOnw0B4PzU7d2LedFk8ajKk@lSTzjF@OpBLVfIEH3uwjp5TNyZ2nfgR9uXo/gPqRzFPL@8odXNqMsR/MYyXxInNEYX984EF0pE9G5HRNgYwityXk4vDv7QDnl/XItXrTBEbxujhS4GakhKayvwc51PMfmLKz0os@LzkoC@Ah3yK6l6TIdXreBrcL4aNmRt3iQazmpG0MvP68Eaywvni/Wd06NSL4y@/nd3cF5n@kSpOdBzYsk4k0QQzX5gmgG/GSgWmL2c5l4EBmBnqznLtV02G@C8F9gX3C889JsNZIqyUzJx7wY4zr7FIs3QlXeSoHDjJ7h@/9RzED83UpuRwM9vDPI0MjgocfoTxL7hObKldYko/qf/tVtcy/WNkPj4z4QgsgK/CCRuRLvOQICiwUVJX7Ex3@AlNAgOPMs/gW5Mh/IO9GHhsjoTAKadB2DGLuDI@KUa3OrEN4LV/iXY9@waL22yDTP@ojhlXjqsIaRxhbtjj5HmNeUwzTUVh@1bX5lOBot5UXz5u1iL5l0joDTAGUTqxZybYeji5I0c7WXYXA41mdvKAfXwhC/Fq0@mlZfqHYbONlGkNk3Qjsx6FJSNABmwUO5qhu1jLicttU3dui/Vpmf4B3INKW@hkZAVOpfNge07zqHCJ7ADCPTnoXdcKWdQ/RT2/pFYeJNM/pgmAkQeiuccXW1aZV2pFP8@iGoUhVuhYXUsTlUxUuthkLN1zMJPFQyfnAcsuhrVGNCj9mFgA7lhiOC97@uPrzYSIg1@aDCN5oKEHqAIGS2HBBUOyQxTLBGuVOScGIAAdewBvXd3b9e1Am9vVZEj@hfA98YtDwW1NhSDsNeumoHIxsKPO97RzMTLp8cuS1t63ypjEZjPaYKvY20SPCiDiY16Ssi7gOcrQw75wEZ@@thrHreeQ/Esu5PcA1YGZvcS5bDmNLB5hZf1Umf2nf3uoVVmuE02aDLdwyxH8AwdsJs64GDmZgQzKyDwB2HWwV@7p98vLxI7Tsq39uqdL/ANbEeURyCJw6/XiZ4@sFYcPzOQf8LFbvIZzR5cH2b0@B/FjtnIQjKdxtEJg827PMSITAzQ9B6A5@I1d9@7bgX@XUHB6u20tUv5BF8qN4i3gntsamVJfahWk6tMsbiM7EuEz3FMPJrX75S51p8mQ6R@uciAF9HrSHFcxMO4wsMIfDi6jzYyu9outfB7WKoN/Ns8h3XOxahbAZharMYYthlvbpaUlU4tZgyxn@@yK1Cdf2H4uEj@FxwczEklqM3wVi0tmOEIIuwVc4lgQx1Ek3VJ28U6d2rNf0oVNRpXubJiW6Dl/QLPWk3G6FKbERuTIrrVprdZOrQrl6bYcn5bpHzMb1SubNHq6KRMrHyZOYzPwjzvn8HdwMLP4URfUjhfqyQVoyYWx7alM/xidoUqLOk4cJcA@KTewKBZu2DBZ1shwT915KaRTbl8@8NPGb5DpH2xcBYGQkmYsezQsIYua/XwVVJPZmcHJnZPqMSO4/v6fvauMhX8MNO9sceDQH8d6AGcBx7iLfum2xu2jvT24zobYfl9k@ofPLAjOlu0JwJtYsSo7WV43ODbwUnGRArmD6pb27Gv/Mj5@pnEHmf7hdWSuZWaSjsV4@AMbhYs3jmy6Z75t0HHJaX1ZWglHCPpxfY6legwKhN1nIljHpS1g9rS8NpJbYkHSFrOJsX1qhUJNhlSPjZZ5VlxZ2BO6DCy0LIaWyTLkViS@Q3t7WUKw356fUtfPb8mQ7hf2Z4BgsoSH4xkIZlJx6DW5FIlJtpKLFmf/09f7SiaYrTIEP4SQ8jAjFd4NuK0j0yaO4@I8Jwkal1hDstQV7j7cBgc2GVJ9Og@cJ0evZeAoKNwQ3OCRpT49h0IBGXDB4xJTIqCH4aK6sXfzHJvphZbB3MBo7Dg6OttsQCPbjY5OibfkMAFg@G1sWVz/b5Mh/gsvQ4ULATaIIxng@jDAxWpL0KhKt9RO9NWP3yEnhMX9AgJx@Nr6HFli4zjbWirWPsMnLIT5nuMZKnM41nO0WdjEcpau5lM312mfWqZ/hCpHCOfcSmkk2@UGpvvzYOF7i93KUml9/fz7WwugXmH9V5Mh1ad0S0cZpVg5gqnHCuLAqzLMMBV0yLxh5fkD5deZGe82ledapn9UdqbDb2KbKy1vJMzbyNpout1m1ku3ZCdVUt2Bb@Juv2pxbS3TPzTJJxzJmcg6s1UWqBiko4iubWK1dpL87au3sE4fLv6a4F4e/rrKEPyYYIp8kWoclhez/QfsGN7CCLA2nG4i3fjdAoPqzVmJKZ1eZUj@hZTJcFAfIInzBMDM/Gyg5haeHfQsbqZdnDSDunJasfXttzbtQsv0Dx0M8x6ghJXNqsBphmWC@KtwQEbGHJ34lWdw6R/JttY3am/zK2X6hyjy0APCBs1qVSst3YUeJpYRllGbS7dYB6J@VaZ2bTo1tEz/6E1kswiDrr30D7Nqge6/pC9jHThFo8XY5m5tV917aZUh@ZeJWV4Gw@GaggFwDIv1gbePbQEZu1utdFfy3l5R12/@B09l@kdhe13m7IXKKaxmmtnaBfPLoU/YZ/hiftrk5m@deKWeq27YkuGlg5eAobmnPa4nHGVoBeuDpF46zjireZIO3t16VP/@e3R5ive@yQjCHYJEXjVn0@CLDa5xz1bgxPY@EEy7pN84mVI9U@bOf22DTP@QKb2mMkHJa1E5F7b4JBXLcPpHFv0wodSJvb@8fP7yudVGmSX@YWGZZilFhDso0zDrTPeYzXcmMLo6cprBySUrdly9Ojyc@X75UJMh@VvHmivWaBvGYKdC92e2rJ0H@5844tIuHUVGHfsTG7rn2hX1RF1f722R7iiAduSQX8vAgWF1o2ddK/gle2lkSItvZbD/SlZ@qZtoMqpwGHpPnN2iWTufOGajRtiGMMBuxRk6VtkwQR/50wbLNpi8TP/Q2AUdpGWXuYJQOBSNCQMWK/WuSD62PUdHi/v1RKT9bzKke58ptIHdulKDFrjFvQekJ9qXyEEvIOUSY9v/x@6tfOOzJkO6b@cgc3jx3IwUjBwlEAOfTYIx5NpSu9QwWRq0X7@H1jcZwj/oeGo390uVZWId7MAgWZUpKxm32gJUZNLeS5rLneJ5XP2zyTCLDHbN4wiz4VQKtnf0tDlTAlHzGQ64cVJF/@HG0udx5@k2W7lM/2C6Z3JAqsKpzz0nUstEt0Qk9uwUdSzg6P5SD98vcxyXuFCTseRfgHaWneaWoxgmdoTPjIh7VhpWOlh2kC6t3@5A1Z@rNxIAufRXkyHxU46mSG6WsZqOpU9YgYRTOQbAeByJn9vUr4@fTi0k5vSzzXM4mbohHYwz299Yp8Hxg1XDOFZCdOS02zizvtCzUPJkaYM31IMmw0uHFedGMttcmEyWkErIuMvwfNgVTcZnltgnsfQiKEz/kiH/JkPyLxw2AgPJydE4l7lyxgWH5RpOZUma8@F8v@TmSRwuW3X88NZ9kekfgV3UunB2kRsDQ0xsYeYTEQFnjv@GD9Ps/sNf1Ymz6pr6fFadbjLSOiEzyySHwGaRAbjuWB80R6iGnR3lMqb0VSbUAJi/f2FLT4sp2aX@FL6H9BuXODqO6hiWxI9hZMgBlLG@fs2ruxFCTs4MozQZUj9WYEwdJ@zCCyELwwbYgosXNVNRHtzZMXXW3WWeMF5Ud28L9V9lyPSgwttKb3yWVmDLUbYFnARWr@LS4NRKsc02vAlLNSwp9w9tSK9wS8Y6mPWeWX7Tc5Bj7xnXDokhOtZsWqm52qluvF6S2XSGzjUZ4r/Au1z6Fg3H8g4MnVYNdRkSB7BysstEQWKXTt7Z12JKz9taZPqH5tTzyOKmgXnFkbAWWArjDJMqYMssOm57eqCNptzSD5n@UYYCH5IN5daNlSZOImu4wUxDazogA4tzOjKXG0dk4Ma3bTLMwrXTUphU/cyoH1kYc3YDy0FwA7EzS3flWRio91jRd8L6s3ZvZfpH0iyMHntOc2RFIEOFcJyYCIbOwMzBYJaly/N4679dPLImQ/BDZrEwbY3rCWnsl/UDvVrWTgddGYdZuvgOggGdv/KfKb1apn9YeBskdrBuPVwdV9kiUIE8A1MvIWCRulBP2bLWqbWCbCND@EdkQ4flVBvN2g0OgA/sDogsAinUMWOTaZ3mmz9/rTKIHxOsAXahSPNM6@2oSW5r4EQmDaYagIqdBHH3pmesWNiK08n0j8LJBf3EqZIcb5FYoF1Yds72B6AiLpJ3tf9PzUS3mQarZfpHYrdMP1UOglhGcjNRygr8MXiS5cSxCGWbjBNCdhu3lOkfgFIOw8vMmJAHMWecI26OmaSWlgVMZuR@fP2uojinJ@R4mwzpnmODfeL008GxqpbFb56ziApHeM7U@r6yTumJmPtHXMmztzC@TYbUr7OSwLhxXFBjoMWb2KZRZjaKOc6xsLTZz2@dGu/e3stZeYcebmy2TP8IpWdYENawJ5/VnHsRbIjLDANw7Z7FNmveow2JeLOJW8r0j8GQOzA2bqVkK@Oq9BUYO5Kujhw6ETkcuduFw7ghhcX6Fm7NniZD/BfmCowZCm8fCSn0uoCKgCcza5ALp/VF@qYn/1zm4d/Y1hWtZfoHVhQ5TRqCRo6DZrP7TM3SDmeVxBUZZFoOvPzjINufW31wkyHTk@kU6H6ZrA/gYjNCYBn@zJ7RgTMqZ8/a0Y9LUv6zml6B1H1aZQj/4FROL3PLKnPXLPaCxQJL77Xkozi1h5PktwZ0M/j4y80mQ6YHWSjm6Fkzz1q4FAilATrTG9Y7MKgxkOJ1RLA9m4LcH782GVJ/yuYMxzlMBgAL0gIvLjr2ufvCVi920s@21cIdjWtIWTVfXaZ/RGwq1Nyxt4nT63uWJnOge@IcN53ZHrzUsb2Q2VJnbl@UDqmfmwypP2Vr2DxFcNzIFm2OsNdMP8CEs2JJBrzJ2wrU@2Uvbj4kuN9oMsR/wWkyccFQ0MxCgT4u7UGGNQJltIz/ZTzH1fOHq/pMDnL8nbr1bj0X6X8BDSH7Yb02x54t6SzpUmSSjqO8ZMhZd/HfIlHLl0fv4fZ@XGWI/8JuQisZaM7pms3My8vKAIaBQbjpN2s5l1vq8ZG3r2mvTzze6Ji8vYEF2p6pK7g6kaPCOFNKhqIlaYpkYdm02Oy4V1RUKFltMmR6IaO3iZNOpRZuyD3dCNZzcIC5Zz9LiKb1FD3cCo0fbzJkeuHM3HzPfqqJDQpE88yZFSOr1mMFm5ntWqO4dCf8ClV7t56t5F8Gsc/ztLyaJCRgFswLa9Bw6JbFi54pmu7Scrj7GdG5envdD5n@kQyH6k/guJWo4XnnIitGreFk24RHiIymdOqwjHbBtb3yAPThXZOhl8k/7ODtOeVK8vukvMEJ8uDSsKA8zb1rUzb/v7ilTP8osbAah5O1OFYCrpxmaW1h4aGMPyYzm5aYY2zTC98d@Fk9bDKIH5FvNiks2o5Z3n2AYzJsYB05@AaeCIvq@tUHenpbnXt2eM@eredY3v4SOOuIJQYclzxxtkop7FONvLccJtsbTgs@pA5hL@oLqau5sJEh@MFKAktfxVZOK6OjUDn3c4Z3BEGSzJD6ZODgPRmjSrZ74myTseRvM0dSMdGHa7IElRNP2XCugWUM1qeltvj8UvgJJblxTT1tMmapUcQt0ezy0Jkv5Rjnfikq0qNjiSNfAcN0ZKeOMJ6cXpJfXnTqSZMh9R8ZmzhGFrJm@tlMRTm@qCNx8s/SDSK5k6X5/@//PVsvtV@a5e9UUT1wKGUKzF4UvmWHSTfPXta4nsueMyo8V9@3yRD8oHGcccuAnfh4P7Jbk8XViXMQsmWWeQD1Bl9vU1jpVt6Pq4wo@WzDsg3mnlh3YUHvWEbOubADrFXk6xecTKPnuONHlwim@778vnkO4R@BOsZk6@xwyQb2rkQWfw4sX@3ZGBOGJcbGobY/wyOU9FaLscn0D8vuPRkFD/eYzihleHBnzVeH5CUbzIn2l5Y@8xZ7@Hl9DqkfSxZ3X@P3Bw8PfeoLR3POka9MYoo8kImzLucrrty@S3AJv1yUiGGTIfUfpbI7C2iOZ2FFcWQoqJfWl7wEeOHthjbNYJlQdXDrXGT6h@d3ZjqjIVLN2TTuCk@IpWNhghc@Vckjf5HRycuf316sMvQyjZ4j/qwQzGHxmUy/VFoxNc3hFwy3d7fVB5nz@QeLP/eutQoy/SPTJ0x85UNh00ySV2vMhOjCkMPEqTPRDRtu@ZX@z4mttUj/i2bJG2utQUSIotwKw9eVwHpxqP7I4jTq6bulYiK3qUxNhvCPicMyOFgqeFaNYRfpS/TwPYwhY2auQHJ86s2awyGpavkomf6RaJm04euRZMwM@8KljXgSg1mkzten7Vz7/tG7z4@uzyH4wcS77jnMmxXCdGpYa22BbSw@YtDccTB6J1nXI@q@unpIRl40GUv9Or64HzmYjjnBiUV4mZ4ufCuZqMzed7/WCLCMJByXJE6T4ZY9DezHZJkCOx18llJjZlythA853ln6bz/Tzf@krt7bfV2t/bdapn94nTh/kdNB2dcVOWWzOr7Qi@0fZuQ8@LG4Nn19NbZb5yLTT8eZMz7ZZp8ld00nsPKlI9my48JyPiIAvxs/n2vDMdXFcGcjQ6YnGw5hlAE/7HObJiGk0AppDOgnglneTFIDFfrUxnY1Gcv0Uw5wZnmRYfQlF3YCsD8bcjwZAAkEvArWTNAxvQ81YxnK2GRI/Tq9i8wVDMzCYhWZ4E6/gYFp1qHA0W01ebvBbtMXFhdv7ovkX4q8W4Gvo5jwccOKpeQZM@O73nQGtjkyz2UtB8/jzl7Zhusy/cOygcpJD0EeOdlzkdGzKoixYM4vnslhrl5Se579epL1p5fO3F75qUz/8BwcZHhbe1rZOvPac9JCHAPH9xJol5ijuvAVtnY530fvWsxRpn9AmcmEPUGYHRpEHs2hYYl0pHJqT0jrlInu/@MfMv1D82V38EppBwwH5FWGPSMHV4BWzqxYmnCzxH/Z92WJ0D9Wx8MqQ@KnfeErp2R6ADurGJaxvDm2B7jPA@jZvMQ@oRln1SV1GXzo9f6V48r0D7AdRp5wENVxphQbJSJTDTPfXNSzFzZnyXnehcE9iOPtlvakJkPwY8TF9swe1wD64qDdUG5oVipUF4b4DVhoO9vNazWOfm8yJH/bS4EDCGlPozsE@HOOAxQzkKXr@Ww6SA38vk1o/TCpbpMh9R8sEKm9DD/E2qPh6/c472qITGXHnu38jLENi4i3S1fymluT6R@B02QsXWE5g36U9lMj5duck8v0FJtfO0lY8NIflURuq@uT6R9wxBkg5LQyj8sOJ5VVPizZqoCwvjrJaHAtYJb@orimr7btaVjilhy5PLA9UxqKgaKOfZ6jvB7PR2a7OQnpK1WUfP3Yb7ewNb83GUv@dmDIsmgmLkjAOEQet4CBEdCXPtilW6JN@L@4ILt62mIGMv5j0Iw0SsyFbem5AH@HWBhnCmzyYbBJJsv9GJSkxQ7ITJb9jSfL/A/P7LGPhSFtRrMZt3GMF/YuszWQEQUjuaRvLTHfioubDImfagkAcR6Ug5HuNdsLwXn5sjZWPFKBZ062vdimQhXGDX5rk221zP/I7OKGRleYZsPKdxnZZ8gGWXXNe@vmtR5XndpJ@nJ/U0evZf5HGTk5gXM6Cm2240sWq2G5VcEyZnoQhQVgnRo3@V854CZD@m85Cmpktih7NtyyKzBlZn41bl9lI0gORu7LktlXr35kGvh8kyHTg2Z2ZrIJAK4HG17cvHSguCovBYPF68lEOpmB1N5BQ/LfZMj0QhY41ILfj4GV3oyFZTuy1on1QSz9cLEs53JdjvXw37s/ba3FyEQ3jvbNJoADsgpdJv0ylTLyfYKRryCwJATduXVm6ftDe1W5eaTJkP7byLIGzmodBrgpni/hzJxaDF/M881xhfU@zb7sOCsY8mnTy6Nl/odmkck4QeFHDtYupLczAy9Tke6AwpCb1MJN0y/SUnTzOaPSrW5L5n9kCxDWjFY6jsL2KYKe8WVBlvHTwsbc6tPCPxZm@e6meLpNhlveyhOXfG/PV0jN8uK5yMZVNi1oGaFcc@s1F2N9Vf2rdm9k@GXCLt/5wkIczoiSgZmZqJE55aKwYEGHTS3L1Z03xRG6spEh00/ZgGyzNPJWGX3EZrfK8YN8rVRkgjmNoh93GEg@12bmtBywzP8YMr4pjCzSrCzmqTKsbiQDkLdqsKUmsrbn4BUlr@TB/06816rV9sj8j4kvCJgMB2uPgCtLDyxxopud@Y6OTIeTmfvukcoPx9/vfqeaPru1WUtepuKz3h1@ds/CCdh4ec8pVsDevsRQRmTbeHfghVorNusWnsr8DyBPTxl0iicZSBCXDkfLpKXjxLpcJRb8EmQ9tZbV12ssWOZ/eBZVVEZwSpUJBJHznOHA9RxRowvfGuk3/ZWtd24zwUzL/I/KitvqHYedRZmwy/f4MdfOuovswCIKRy@stOGfV0vOoK1F5n8MbHLPfMda4lgrzeTHEBOnPPGlePIfBmLyQYaSHqgjB9TFfSCZDZNl/odmYK6wRmBMfF0rGxMT3dJUBuliGTn@Yrlz4@9LqmDX8zdrPFnmfyR2lOYBqhRnYGEOHJFgoSkxGzY4cZqOnO0a@wQYnv4AUtZkyPygmW8DKYkln5zxyXckVZawReK6tDbUafGjoBpnyv9wKZn/MXJ4mbRHRHZcYCPBPzjmHACfupked2AZaOfvDUZm9/Saxn9oMibJV7JSAhsCDsNxrqwznzluqnKCiWFXysAG/E79yz71I/e@v2Llw2qjZP5H9ARQOspgHYnviWUVP99rMcKE95wU0xepMWqvKnE/Hv9j21qW6WOcvToaGn@mbkdhAIQf9tDwVXkAyXHBoL8frtvx047fmgzhH@7/AQ)

Requires a local binary file named `z` of size `7313` (which is the genome of SARS-Cov-2 encoded by mapping each base to 2-bits and then `zlib.compress`ing that number):

```python
00000000: 789c 2d97 f95b 9a07 a2b6 4116 2105 c4b0  x.-..[....A.!...
00000010: 048c 5a4c 4463 4fce f445 c0a0 0503 2a2e  ..ZLDcO..E....*.
00000020: 292a 0a28 24a0 107d 51d3 24d5 086a 326a  )*.($..}Q.$..j2j
00000030: 40c5 a5c5 1d10 ad26 da68 6ce7 cc74 9226  @......&.hl..t.&
00000040: 3dd3 ce74 7a50 5c5b d7b8 929a 8875 4b3a  =..tzP\[.....uK:
00000050: cbd1 1a13 d3a6 9933 df75 7df7 3ff0 fc78  .......3.u}.?..x
00000060: 3f37 3edd 115b d13f 6ced eb33 dcaf 653c  ?7>..[.?l..3..e<
00000070: 006a d316 a152 f3b4 d9fe 4d38 c777 2b68  .j...R....M8.w+h
00000080: db5b 2034 2143 9d39 ae3f 914f 5655 841f  .[ 4!C.9.?.OVU..
00000090: b8df f7f8 7622 fc6f 09c1 ed01 3b27 ff38  ....v".o....;'.8
000000a0: f170 6157 f7e2 1ae6 931d fa9f 64ed 9fdb  .paW........d...
000000b0: 8261 b720 3983 ffb8 f7e1 d148 d8a3 0fa6  .a. 9......H....
000000c0: cb7e 8277 bdfc 5c41 4b4f b633 dd05 4b58  .~.w..\AKO.3..KX
000000d0: d92f 9027 366c ce27 a2c1 8473 6fcc 7d28  ./.'6l.'...so.}(
000000e0: dfaa e3b6 c277 1e73 af2e fe67 7954 c1d7  .....w.s...gyT..
000000f0: 77a7 4f69 bd42 2bdf 0a9c fe47 4a7f 24f2  w.Oi.B+....GJ.$.
00000100: ab52 5ac5 f0e2 aeb0 6c7d ba37 fffd 3f3f  .RZ.....l}.7..??
00000110: 208d c3d4 e5df 9744 669d 812f f1e9 0b59   ......Df../...Y
00000120: 8b1a 857f e184 cf3d 79eb bd12 f28b d7b1  .......=y.......
00000130: e7d7 4267 c10a e68f ac83 0bb4 950d d243  ..Bg...........C
00000140: d4d5 7b8d 2477 ab1d f307 b051 8d77 9956  ..{.$w.....Q.w.V
00000150: f7bc 1b22 26b3 1f27 8add bb1f 2d0e b255  ..."&..'....-..U
00000160: 6b6c 5c51 2e4c 4af2 b22e c0b4 1592 5f45  kl\Q.LJ......._E
00000170: 7d7c 8647 b734 84d8 a641 e75d c7a6 cb4a  }|.G.4...A.]...J
00000180: 5807 f057 fa37 e2c7 cee4 ffbd 433a bfd9  X..W.7......C:..
00000190: 277a 823e 1fb8 c44c c0ec a5a1 238b 5ecf  'z.>...L....#.^.
000001a0: 6048 4f2b bf80 4cdb 1ff1 97d3 3323 3495  `HO+..L.....3#4.
000001b0: 5c8a 4f9f c40c c8a0 98fe d620 7157 c1f3  \.O........ qW..
000001c0: fa8d 2bb8 2f7c 84ec e3ee 853c d4c9 cce9  ..+./|.....<....
000001d0: df68 7086 17eb 4c94 11d8 794a 564e 559d  .hp...L...yJVNU.
000001e0: 3e74 71ed 9fe4 3827 b9f9 26e0 7c54 fa1f  >tq...8'..&.|T..
000001f0: 9934 09d8 5d29 3d6f 552d 8c67 5ba2 bdc2  .4..])=oU-.g[...
00000200: a072 e292 eecf 02c8 4b9a 0727 a48d 03e3  .r......K..'....
00000210: c927 3361 33c2 ab68 85d8 996a dee5 9306  .'3a3..h...j....
00000220: ac65 e926 d9de adf9 e8c9 1ca9 25eb 4a2d  .e.&........%.J-
00000230: 7c03 97b0 da70 d279 3481 7fec b3f3 58f9  |....p.y4.....X.
00000240: 0f32 d4d4 04b4 abfc 4ba1 4533 378f ee8c  .2......K.E37...
00000250: ca2a 0a64 adb1 06b3 eb61 6b26 4b0d 46f2  .*.d.....ak&K.F.
00000260: 249b ba37 0174 86bd d179 2057 d022 b3a0  $..7.t...y W."..
00000270: ec34 fa85 6fb1 5e95 aa25 6859 e968 3ead  .4..o.^..%hY.h>.
00000280: f87d af05 0c09 7aec 2cb3 921d fd36 cf8a  .}....z.,....6..
00000290: e960 5af7 0565 2b83 4551 d012 468a 18e6  .`Z..e+.EQ..F...
000002a0: 6672 96ab 9aa2 a74b d210 d7b0 fcd2 85a6  fr.....K........
000002b0: d0cb e7d3 9f31 ba94 13a4 9047 faac 27e7  .....1.....G..'.
000002c0: 936a 653f 5af5 029a 71f5 91a2 e2b6 7e82  .je?Z...q.....~.
000002d0: 5cbc 84a9 9435 b290 6705 8b67 2985 19c0  \....5..g..g)...
000002e0: d207 d1ce 913c c710 f935 dcf9 a1d4 eaea  .....<...5......
000002f0: 4aa7 4c75 6f99 08c9 e4b4 94ee f6ba ccaf  J.Luo...........
00000300: b76c e903 06ee 9c96 19a7 dcdc 0157 2663  .l...........W&c
00000310: ec30 396b e119 2b9d 427c 5458 fb24 367f  .09k..+.B|TX.$6.
00000320: f16d ea12 e9d4 1bb7 80e9 2ece 3849 8e3b  .m..........8I.;
00000330: 5b70 5cac d6da 5f47 f375 2b2f 086b cdd5  [p\..._G.u+/.k..
00000340: 70ec a9e3 930e 6924 ba99 81a1 057c d29f  p.....i$.....|..
00000350: f86c 4955 3a33 a95f ca3f d56b a313 0ab8  .lIU:3._.?.k....
00000360: 592a 964f 26a9 9bc7 dfbb 8d5a afa5 df52  Y*.O&......Z...R
00000370: 15b7 a974 5c3f d6ec 3898 e545 6f7b bf73  ...t\?..8..Eo{.s
00000380: 150c 06ab f156 0bb0 8ace b5f8 cd2d 22f3  .....V.......-".
00000390: 9ce8 e568 e57c be27 174f 5267 810c 2a42  ...h.|.'.ORg..*B
000003a0: ba9d cd5c ca20 6592 f272 b880 e486 c591  ...\. e..r......
000003b0: 4b6a 5d2d 75de bc86 101e 68c0 8824 25fb  Kj]-u.....h..$%.
000003c0: 7822 32ae 9af8 dc4e 9a9e f665 4232 9e83  x"2....N...eB2..
000003d0: b435 85b9 4214 fab3 1550 64b2 5d68 b5b1  .5..B....Pd.]h..
000003e0: 9843 9041 52af 7e31 4809 efc5 27ac 0f41  .C.AR.~1H...'..A
000003f0: f6ea 3f89 8d82 16c3 18b3 e6df 80a2 6a4f  ..?...........jO
00000400: b361 5676 8c00 aa1d 6d06 2fe9 52a1 6cd3  .aVv....m./.R.l.
00000410: a948 7fb7 7ea6 47b5 3f70 8d2f ac57 a655  .H..~.G.?p./.W.U
00000420: e42f 16cb da12 8fc8 e825 4cac 7ec0 266f  ./.......%L.~.&o
00000430: 54c9 9527 da17 d403 8698 3041 b2a5 e28c  T..'......0A....
00000440: eef8 6dda c064 932b c803 a1d7 fdd0 ec3d  ..m..d.+.......=
00000450: 3d09 0caa 5e39 c89c 6978 ae46 76b0 b745  =...^9..ix.Fv..E
00000460: 59e0 fc36 ddf0 283d 42e1 1278 e719 ffeb  Y..6..(=B..x....
00000470: a7eb 50c9 807d b4ec a5aa d32d 2b24 1576  ..P..}.....-+$.v
00000480: 23a3 7ce2 05c7 888f aeea a3bc e48e ca79  #.|............y
00000490: dc23 4965 7bf8 52da 6529 f1c9 d8c4 be26  .#Ie{.R.e).....&
000004a0: a3d9 61f3 be31 1c93 3944 8a55 bd9a c6c2  ..a..1..9D.U....
000004b0: f76a f814 6847 419a 7cf4 7375 8256 7d2e  .j..hGA.|.su.V}.
000004c0: 5eba 500b 8011 ea03 91a2 d52d f552 95fc  ^.P........-.R..
000004d0: b04b d0d5 5aa7 6e50 1d66 5450 3d67 e0c6  .K..Z.nP.fTP=g..
000004e0: 9064 80a6 ae40 c93a d88b 7cfc 426f 5d65  .d...@.:..|.Bo]e
000004f0: e321 6f95 d789 289e a51a ac19 d27b 201e  .!o...(......{ .
00000500: ed09 9543 027b c119 9fec 909e b9c9 fc84  ...C.{..........
00000510: eeb0 5484 abc2 0356 ac5c d520 f6a0 b602  ..T....V.\. ....
00000520: 5736 f903 eda6 93d7 4a0f 8b79 ae70 fc64  W6......J..y.p.d
00000530: 837b 2597 cc21 49c2 b381 e276 f66e 1a9f  .{%..!I....v.n..
00000540: 00c9 9524 daab 274e b9b1 233e 5af9 831a  ...$..'N..#>Z...
00000550: 48e3 e888 e886 2055 4b52 eec7 de56 1277  H..... UKR...V.w
00000560: c828 81e4 e52c 683e 8cb3 6f00 8a0f 1429  .(...,h>..o....)
00000570: 2b6c 476a 07a7 5ac5 c1e7 5cbd dec8 5e37  +lGj..Z...\...^7
00000580: 1998 f6c3 9e3d e694 a282 bdfc d239 4f3d  .....=.......9O=
00000590: 780a 8941 673f e5eb 689b aa31 f6bd 8961  x..Ag?..h..1...a
000005a0: 39d3 95d3 65eb ce9c d0af c347 92b7 d4b4  9...e......G....
000005b0: 4410 aa2f 1dd4 e532 ee71 d332 a8d2 f802  D../...2.q.2....
000005c0: 5bd9 7837 8620 ba91 77ab 6e68 11b1 b1db  [.x7. ..w.nh....
000005d0: 4461 d69c a236 127d 0ab9 7661 b6b0 82b4  Da...6.}..va....
000005e0: 6018 0af7 fbda 4da1 2a3f d653 334f 08fe  `.....M.*?.S3O..
000005f0: 0aa0 40bd 62a0 1dec 95f5 23e1 521e d709  ..@.b.....#.R...
00000600: a32e 603f 51f2 2c78 e182 2b0a 8eee daec  ..`?Q.,x..+.....
00000610: c3d2 46ac 7dbd 67d2 36dd f7c5 08c7 d024  ..F.}.g.6......$
00000620: 3141 cc99 e3a7 7592 b9de fa5c 775b b151  1A....u....\w[.Q
00000630: 4985 bc15 8648 664d 47e2 6784 5a6a 472d  I....HfMG.g.ZjG-
00000640: 545f b626 1e68 3e8b 77bc 0414 49f2 948c  T_.&.h>.w...I...
00000650: 8fbc cf4a 73f7 bcef 8c79 5db5 e639 d312  ...Js....y]..9..
00000660: c477 5823 ecf1 d5cb dbfb 3c62 e5ad 2f1e  .wX#......<b../.
00000670: 90f2 c6ea f5a3 3c69 4f6f 4efa 45da ca30  ......<iOoN.E..0
00000680: 5356 fd85 f3cd 2201 85d4 6f25 e693 c439  SV...."...o%...9
00000690: aa9d 9fb5 3a53 2487 e067 0918 a308 f4b9  ....:S$..g......
000006a0: 1271 7c31 be14 9bd6 bd56 c7f5 6c00 5226  .q|1.....V..l.R&
000006b0: 3e39 1deb bd26 e064 1868 0a25 5060 a328  >9...&.d.h.%P`.(
000006c0: 7ca9 5f3b d2ee c128 e298 2778 1a05 ce01  |._;...(..'x....
000006d0: 3123 10cd 1255 5c23 4e6f 21fc a1da 7b53  1#...U\#No!...{S
000006e0: 4f19 280e dd15 636a cad1 5001 4cd9 4184  O.(...cj..P.L.A.
000006f0: 98b2 8431 defc 1d68 d511 20e2 4d14 22a0  ...1...h.. .M.".
00000700: eebd 06e8 1e44 12c0 2f4f aa40 321a 91c5  .....D../O.@2...
00000710: 9955 d8f3 1449 107e b3c7 9c35 e8dd 3d0a  .U...I.~...5..=.
00000720: 847a 723d a3a0 ae9e 1334 3f79 acd4 87df  .zr=.....4?y....
00000730: 0291 fe0a cd32 447a e28a b990 97de 280f  .....2Dz......(.
00000740: cd8e 0781 c2f3 6a48 4d12 3bd0 6b90 6d2a  ......jHM.;.k.m*
00000750: 4430 8c8a 844f 2388 c44a aae4 c7fb e835  D0...O#..J.....5
00000760: ae9f 28bb 02d6 c2c7 8b92 6503 cc56 4cd1  ..(.......e..VL.
00000770: ce30 9a5e 4910 0d58 efc6 5d05 57be 60d8  .0.^I..X..].W.`.
00000780: f003 c980 fe27 0321 8023 5925 1dc0 acd5  .....'.!.#Y%....
00000790: a097 7882 c88c 8d62 36fa 66c3 7de7 94ef  ..x....b6.f.}...
000007a0: 14ab c7ab f349 4516 694f 7d3f cdd8 e28c  .....IE.iO}?....
000007b0: 0372 d8f3 3bbd bd06 352b bd91 ae32 b28b  .r..;...5+...2..
000007c0: a28e 1de3 0372 3f5b fd63 a2c2 541a 1881  .....r?[.c..T...
000007d0: 97c0 f361 c924 ba84 3ddf 122e bd31 e6d0  ...a.$..=....1..
000007e0: 74de 804f d8aa b290 7ec1 1bbe 6373 5eac  t..O....~...cs^.
000007f0: c2bf e66f 2324 b024 e440 ac23 d006 39e7  ...o#$.$.@.#..9.
00000800: 2359 905b b5be e159 5d25 8bb8 7449 a8d1  #Y.[...Y]%..tI..
00000810: 2532 0618 f0c1 37de 6edb 0166 ba18 0b26  %2....7.n..f...&
00000820: 9d13 2b32 8ac7 5b52 c3e2 9494 5fe2 3029  ..+2..[R...._.0)
00000830: 1a42 5d0f 391d 9b96 d8f1 fb87 5e1c 06d6  .B].9.......^...
00000840: 5cf8 9740 41d2 f6a8 55d9 9ecd c112 1607  \..@A...U.......
00000850: 541e a2a6 b145 f9a5 34e9 c5c2 0692 4a68  T....E..4.....Jh
00000860: ec46 38b3 a7e4 1a57 fe80 8801 5a67 b710  .F8....W....Zg..
00000870: af76 a540 4ab4 3323 5f9c 8e54 4f9c 8038  .v.@J.3#_..TO..8
00000880: 1bf0 287e 8ad6 1c38 1e4a 6aae 37d0 2753  ..(~...8.Jj.7.'S
00000890: e366 dbd6 b0dc bda0 932e fff8 9c58 0ccc  .f...........X..
000008a0: 646d ad87 b85a 1dd7 7ecb dd1d a048 c092  dm...Z..~....H..
000008b0: 88a6 99f5 ce66 f051 e10e e6de 2dc7 9397  .....f.Q....-...
000008c0: f705 5fd9 887b 6a58 132d b718 e2bb ed45  .._..{jX.-.....E
000008d0: 8e1f 68ef b5aa e30a eccb 3845 7025 e0d5  ..h.......8Ep%..
000008e0: c066 5820 e949 a8dd 6b05 bdd1 f0d9 3e46  .fX .I..k.....>F
000008f0: 4d26 ca69 64e7 1ffd c4f5 117c 2af0 d941  M&.id......|*..A
00000900: 15de 7288 9c9b cbde 31fb 4d93 e5b0 a853  ..r.....1.M....S
00000910: 94d1 ad97 956c 5d57 c91e 8c11 50c3 d5bd  .....l]W....P...
00000920: 522b 12e1 d407 d0fe 150f e684 6e9d 0435  R+..........n..5
00000930: 9a08 d00e 4dd4 59fc 9ee1 79cc 8df8 387f  ....M.Y...y...8.
00000940: ee2e a6e4 5d5f 4504 ae1a 0f5f 852e 95c0  ....]_E...._....
00000950: 2663 af88 f29f 2028 487c b7a8 c93e 721c  &c.... (H|...>r.
00000960: aaed 4406 d272 f7a0 a801 6825 258c 7f18  ..D..r....h%%...
00000970: 499c f380 78b6 e33b 9fed 8882 723d 7d3c  I...x..;....r=}<
00000980: 7864 b13b a689 e1d1 9ec1 afe2 d27c c5b9  xd.;.........|..
00000990: e945 1357 a0c9 c009 4f0a 4c55 f24f 6607  .E.W....O.LU.Of.
000009a0: 0490 a64b 874c f97f 2f14 ad21 6b8f 5a84  ...K.L../..!k.Z.
000009b0: 7e14 7f9a b770 44c9 f77d 6179 06d6 5417  ~....pD..}ay..T.
000009c0: 6770 80f1 639b e5c7 24ea 4ef9 4dd4 1c0a  gp..c...$.N.M...
000009d0: 69eb 0073 ab3a 82cd b0ae 6988 5efa f250  i..s.:....i.^..P
000009e0: 0b37 1dfb 8ac1 0587 2bb9 60b5 fadc 9857  .7......+.`....W
000009f0: 65e2 5d47 5648 91e8 41f8 c76c 1787 dc23  e.]GVH..A..l...#
00000a00: 60cf 509a ee5e 2136 f32b 47ca b912 f4f9  `.P..^!6.+G.....
00000a10: eb70 5e53 d5a6 7842 9d81 d899 bd61 e929  .p^S..xB.....a.)
00000a20: ca55 0a1d 831b f47e d732 a473 c03d 60d9  .U.....~.2.s.=`.
00000a30: e988 df83 f631 ab56 3fe5 db05 d7d1 8710  .....1.V?.......
00000a40: dcc0 695f a783 1c27 0863 1e83 00d9 5bcd  ..i_...'.c....[.
00000a50: 3c41 5f63 7e6b 63fb b25f a91c caeb c684  <A_c~kc.._......
00000a60: 95a7 5d6d bbc1 7d5f 2b17 7412 1dfe 5e98  ..]m..}_+.t...^.
00000a70: cb9c 0112 cfb5 e7a8 7b97 9f67 a349 d4e4  ........{..g.I..
00000a80: ca48 8212 842f d62a daf2 0017 a5ec 630f  .H.../.*......c.
00000a90: 8eb5 51fc 3788 4e34 8546 a804 0d32 6e62  ..Q.7.N4.F...2nb
00000aa0: f2c5 3cfc ab42 8360 2991 af35 b09c 9e20  ..<..B.`)..5...
00000ab0: e726 a00e 516e b355 20fd 9536 af11 4369  .&..Qn.U ..6..Ci
00000ac0: e787 a10d bed0 6f8b 2996 9f60 2808 8c20  ......o.)..`(..
00000ad0: 8b80 f840 d64e e3a3 abc6 dc38 8908 636d  ...@.N.....8..cm
00000ae0: be1a ee71 1c06 0172 8fe1 eca3 4648 0ab7  ...q...r....FH..
00000af0: 2aa9 c1f7 34eb ef82 b064 af98 9dd9 1ad8  *...4....d......
00000b00: 71c7 1193 ca3c c008 0f36 1722 89dd 8937  q....<...6."...7
00000b10: 5459 0cd6 dcd4 9bc5 4c97 911d 8ab5 dff1  TY......L.......
00000b20: 56c2 09c3 1ccf 846b fcde e91f e0a9 c791  V......k........
00000b30: 28f9 f9d2 51a4 7c1c 803d 5dc5 3be0 13ce  (...Q.|..=].;...
00000b40: 025c 0fa4 42d8 48d4 a227 849c 7cbc c378  .\..B.H..'..|..x
00000b50: c0c7 fcdb b73f d330 48fa 6714 cfac f35e  .....?.0H.g....^
00000b60: 0041 6074 54e7 ac78 c624 46e5 3ca7 7cfa  .A`tT..x.$F.<.|.
00000b70: a9de 3f2e a922 8dde 2405 5e39 a7ad dd43  ..?.."..$.^9...C
00000b80: d6d1 db8c 4e93 2458 941e de52 3046 a973  ....N.$X...R0F.s
00000b90: 8483 752b fac0 1612 e635 9d19 32d0 9ed8  ..u+.....5..2...
00000ba0: 54eb 4f9a ad66 3fc1 ca92 3d34 0633 ccd0  T.O..f?...=4.3..
00000bb0: bbbd 672e 1282 6ea6 4ad2 08de dcec 06d7  ..g...n.J.......
00000bc0: fceb 563c 0f55 b4c4 6c1b 3859 757a 77e2  ..V<.U..l.8Yuzw.
00000bd0: f63a 8eb8 17c5 76a2 484a f612 8dcd 5c4b  .:....v.HJ....\K
00000be0: 65c3 de63 6df7 6ede cddf 5745 b2da aa1e  e..cm.n...WE....
00000bf0: 5a19 a49b 35f1 abe0 eaa6 9252 58b5 0d72  Z...5......RX..r
00000c00: 3c34 1c3f 258f 3867 b729 e036 499b 6e67  <4.?%.8g.).6I.ng
00000c10: e22d 6c76 cac7 48c5 769f 2619 d3dc af21  .-lv..H.v.&....!
00000c20: 670b a517 27b9 6013 85d0 7215 f36b aaad  g...'.`...r..k..
00000c30: 9431 d7e5 2bc3 d08d 93e2 029e 25c8 04dd  .1..+.......%...
00000c40: f899 164d 2e41 bcb6 1c37 5b91 7ae2 63cf  ...M.A...7[.z.c.
00000c50: 134e fba5 ae50 ccfa 1f29 da34 4e78 7d98  .N...P...).4Nx}.
00000c60: e44e 0905 6c07 af97 9662 d45b c099 19ea  .N..l....b.[....
00000c70: 33ac e440 f7d6 91c2 64f9 6e55 558e 7cff  3..@....d.nUU.|.
00000c80: 76e5 9b30 6491 d654 daa3 5cc2 7b1b 0499  v..0d..T..\.{...
00000c90: 0245 aeb4 7868 b772 14ba 7ebb e073 6ac9  .E..xh.r..~..sj.
00000ca0: 6e92 6229 2242 6c63 c00d 6637 8e31 d740  n.b)"Blc..f7.1.@
00000cb0: 7283 bac3 febe ff72 e525 9830 033a 27a3  r......r.%.0.:'.
00000cc0: ddbe db18 bc49 ced7 fef5 5a0a 8f3e dfcd  .....I....Z..>..
00000cd0: dd6b 9908 6534 dc79 dafc e08c b427 93cf  .k..e4.y.....'..
00000ce0: 54cb 760b 1856 1faa 7a8a f8d0 fc0a 6a27  T.v..V..z.....j'
00000cf0: 293a cdef 1dff 5ab4 5f4a 58f7 6526 9cff  ):....Z._JX.e&..
00000d00: cbd9 d68a 2b25 73ed ef42 48ff 03fb 7a78  ....+%s..BH...zx
00000d10: eada e7c8 f7de d92a d78c b0be f3be e9c6  .......*........
00000d20: b650 1349 a38d 9035 718f cc84 0975 f72d  .P.I...5q....u.-
00000d30: 947d 3107 42a3 a390 30df 2345 5a8f 004d  .}1.B...0.#EZ..M
00000d40: 5fab 4ac1 1742 8d65 987e 3327 2db1 029a  _.J..B.e.~3'-...
00000d50: ef17 f77e 58b2 4f76 cc47 f4cf 9124 aae5  ...~X.Ov.G...$..
00000d60: e5c3 9355 ee23 1bb0 c452 f164 3b42 9552  ...U.#...R.d;B.R
00000d70: 1914 2b76 b2e6 041e 29b2 e7dc 44c8 a8ec  ..+v....)...D...
00000d80: d359 fce5 a1cb 36cf c98b 234f 4b30 24c5  .Y....6...#OK0$.
00000d90: 88d8 3cd7 fb0f 4923 de39 9195 ed47 6c8b  ..<...I#.9...Gl.
00000da0: b7ec 660d cdbc cd42 53cf 5ebe e9fb e210  ..f....BS.^.....
00000db0: 301a 05c7 370d 2455 0972 c36e bac9 e12b  0...7.$U.r.n...+
00000dc0: ed80 abde 085e 430a 0a9f 6148 31cb 41fb  .....^C...aH1.A.
00000dd0: 8f76 64b5 d8df e311 31a7 135c 3e17 a44c  .vd.....1..\>..L
00000de0: 84d9 2bb1 2b1c b5c1 b41a 2490 a880 cec1  ..+.+.....$.....
00000df0: dbd5 4ad8 43cd e442 0a0c cb1d 6c62 386c  ..J.C..B....lb8l
00000e00: 3c1f 75d7 e337 8111 61f0 1cc9 d8fc 839f  <.u..7..a.......
00000e10: d171 649e c224 3484 ddaa da5a afe0 a6e2  .qd..$4....Z....
00000e20: 35b3 e7ec 17dd e8d1 06b5 0604 dc68 f9f8  5............h..
00000e30: d9af c508 eb72 4018 cc3c 96e9 3064 662a  .....r@..<..0df*
00000e40: 8f63 0569 ea0a 58dd b3dd 244e c23f e0cb  .c.i..X...$N.?..
00000e50: 9a93 def1 7920 9395 e0d2 5461 f297 302c  ....y ....Ta..0,
00000e60: a59a 055c e21e 0c11 d7f2 aebc 4bb7 d580  ...\........K...
00000e70: 09eb 8e10 a830 79b7 dccf 2060 d14f c157  .....0y... `.O.W
00000e80: 1374 5b90 afbc ad17 2581 9f68 c8f4 c4f8  .t[.....%..h....
00000e90: 2384 5edf 4dbd df0f 5b77 d727 6ae3 4729  #.^.M...[w.'j.G)
00000ea0: 897d 7e9d 68ba 14bf 40f7 ffb3 66b5 24cb  .}~.h...@...f.$.
00000eb0: 57bc df66 4525 7323 c156 441a e03d c958  W..fE%s#.VD..=.X
00000ec0: b810 643c ed35 7386 c48c bb96 646a 35ce  ..d<.5s.....dj5.
00000ed0: 139e d881 ca0f adcd b609 867b bcc3 51a5  ...........{..Q.
00000ee0: f327 ae4c d187 4eb1 9303 277e 19d4 1010  .'.L..N...'~....
00000ef0: 797b 8b75 c18f 22c0 06f8 5a1c 00cd c6b4  y{.u.."...Z.....
00000f00: 993f 7a2a 226e 41e2 b392 c932 dc7d a5e8  .?z*"nA....2.}..
00000f10: 3331 555b 043d 151a e097 f208 7075 1926  31U[.=......pu.&
00000f20: 131d 479b 6177 151e 74d6 6c6d fdfd 75cc  ..G.aw..t.lm..u.
00000f30: 043a ce4e 68a1 ffe4 7b70 95b4 08bd 926f  .:.Nh...{p.....o
00000f40: 10d0 1522 88a8 feaa d4b9 fca8 be5b 9399  ...".........[..
00000f50: db2a c61d 5350 937c 4937 2759 0446 77f7  .*..SP.|I7'Y.Fw.
00000f60: 055d 6f5b 6acd eb6f 008c 6ef6 a42c 2799  .]o[j..o..n..,'.
00000f70: 6a64 b1bf 3e39 e659 a573 5f50 6b14 2752  jd..>9.Y.s_Pk.'R
00000f80: cb86 d645 8626 86d1 92ad caa0 b256 c865  ...E.&.......V.e
00000f90: ed40 9128 0a48 4212 67b5 e8d2 e8fd 5bf9  .@.(.HB.g.....[.
00000fa0: f0d5 aa11 ed57 d431 ea81 f335 6610 6609  .....W.1...5f.f.
00000fb0: 2a42 23e6 b8ee 8d8b 454d 4660 3809 b8d4  *B#.....EMF`8...
00000fc0: 3b7e 5811 2414 8c85 02a9 7781 f0a4 909d  ;~X.$.....w.....
00000fd0: c9d0 1cd1 b20d 6a7c 31f4 181f 4d0a 12e6  ......j|1...M...
00000fe0: 7dea 09e9 6572 24ae 7c98 2346 162b 728e  }...er$.|.#F.+r.
00000ff0: de97 20c3 a049 e2cd d630 9e95 b327 68f2  .. ..I...0...'h.
00001000: 3475 30ea 5575 2590 edae 7375 1994 d522  4u0.Uu%...su..."
00001010: 7e5a 287c 1747 1999 2c34 d777 cd53 6981  ~Z(|.G..,4.w.Si.
00001020: bfe6 ef9e f5bb 6d27 7f21 0885 36c2 ef91  ......m'.!..6...
00001030: 498a e102 eb9b c5d4 6e76 fa64 d55e 12e0  I.......nv.d.^..
00001040: 78af 14b4 21a5 2460 4f00 990a 4b68 ee94  x...!.$`O...Kh..
00001050: f41e 09ef b117 de56 6d11 3cc5 59ee d83e  .......Vm.<.Y..>
00001060: bb25 beeb 14a4 c6e2 b4c2 ada5 dc24 d950  .%...........$.P
00001070: 80bd ff79 0737 6b78 a509 87ff d9ff 18e5  ...y.7kx........
00001080: 02ea 878d 42ef 1bb8 6349 5f3a 9334 4cfd  ....B...cI_:.4L.
00001090: 4b44 0aac c78f c418 15c7 365c fc61 a218  KD........6\.a..
000010a0: c092 d0ca 797a 93be 5364 6098 a51b 11a7  ....yz..Sd`.....
000010b0: 2edd d0c5 610c 7352 74f2 6d29 81bf e2a4  ....a.sRt.m)....
000010c0: 47e8 8e72 3234 4caa d77f dfaa 13dc eab8  G..r24L.........
000010d0: 9ccd 9167 6e69 16bb 62d0 5185 8c65 82ac  ...gni..b.Q..e..
000010e0: aab4 3f7b f0c3 45cc 37ce 13eb 52c0 655e  ..?{..E.7...R.e^
000010f0: 7173 e1b3 4277 7a3b c995 5a62 7193 44d0  qs..Bwz;..Zbq.D.
00001100: 237b f08f 5a45 e8e3 1672 797b ca2f 5cd5  #{..ZE...ry{./\.
00001110: fc09 eadd 0b1c de42 c918 1cdd 2d44 7725  .......B....-Dw%
00001120: 319e 5867 bc96 f3ce a701 332d 3907 5d31  1.Xg......3-9.]1
00001130: cba2 6674 ddd9 acb4 127b 2571 3887 2fc1  ..ft.....{%q8./.
00001140: e1f3 1ecb 4637 d4e1 c4b1 d947 dd04 d069  ....F7.....G...i
00001150: 412a 2ba5 2177 f799 9b06 705d c6c8 5936  A*+.!w....p]..Y6
00001160: a447 fb66 12ed afa8 27b4 e5b9 dadc 4ea7  .G.f....'.....N.
00001170: 9684 4e63 ef10 0097 4f64 ace9 7962 8f5f  ..Nc....Od..yb._
00001180: 5160 6de2 6988 8c0d 6f43 707d 4cad d0a0  Q`m.i...oCp}L...
00001190: cf96 32bc 8b44 1737 9e45 be21 fad3 ab71  ..2..D.7.E.!...q
000011a0: 8ee6 5189 73c4 8234 e4d4 3850 3913 e41a  ..Q.s..4..8P9...
000011b0: 1ca3 e726 dc19 9b9b 12ab 83f4 e717 9af2  ...&............
000011c0: 3e6b d459 10da 3a1f b508 2cab a89c 1f7d  >k.Y..:...,....}
000011d0: c75b 8501 4547 c2b4 0869 6d7d d777 f850  .[..EG...im}.w.P
000011e0: f8eb ec03 ac33 bb6a 098f 5988 7b78 eaab  .....3.j..Y.{x..
000011f0: 5b98 aa49 bf7b b793 20b7 39c1 5af8 13e7  [..I.{.. .9.Z...
00001200: 4653 150f 26f8 dcfb 8c23 110b d824 afa0  FS..&....#...$..
00001210: 37c9 d5e9 b6d6 f8a1 5065 ef6e 52f6 680d  7.......Pe.nR.h.
00001220: 66ce d2aa d90b 580f f913 0773 e41e b651  f.....X....s...Q
00001230: 838d e921 72e7 e44b 82a4 03c6 c28e 2d7b  ...!r..K......-{
00001240: 6720 231c ee5f 247d 2bbf e252 d3ee 05d2  g #.._$}+..R....
00001250: 1a62 62a4 ae64 ce2f 5919 c0da ba86 2904  .bb..d./Y.....).
00001260: 4bbc a5fa 797c 152d a9bd a9de 8aee e20e  K...y|.-........
00001270: 3de1 f3a2 2ddf c5c5 dc32 1d8a 86f9 c1b4  =...-....2......
00001280: 7e53 87c9 46f5 939d 49ee 4bc7 d0b0 307b  ~S..F...I.K...0{
00001290: 23a4 bddf c092 4d41 06f8 328b 0f1f 25a8  #.....MA..2...%.
000012a0: 757d 2b5a a9e3 a529 0b83 6374 041f 8db2  u}+Z...)..ct....
000012b0: e128 837c 319c 5fba 6736 1725 7024 055d  .(.|1._.g6.%p$.]
000012c0: 98f8 fb6e 616b e2b1 9203 cfca d350 ab05  ...nak.......P..
000012d0: 4bf1 ce6d 5418 a845 e815 4f19 d38d 0086  K..mT..E..O.....
000012e0: 85bf dab1 3cdb 75f6 4827 2a01 41ce 82b6  ....<.u.H'*.A...
000012f0: a763 b94e 911e 8395 ca6c 825b 08c6 06d6  .c.N.....l.[....
00001300: 7dda f44f 0522 6fa4 6b4f 46b1 884f 335d  }..O."o.kOF..O3]
00001310: 384e 8af9 c169 8db5 3829 642b 265e e305  8N...i..8)d+&^..
00001320: 0055 cb2e ffb6 341b fb12 2cfc 7650 2804  .U....4...,.vP(.
00001330: cb2d c672 dbfc 8cd0 8588 bbc9 8011 a9df  .-.r............
00001340: 9d20 ed50 f38e bff9 565a 86af 31f9 4a36  . .P....VZ..1.J6
00001350: 91b7 f47b 9936 ffff b59d 3319 f856 21b8  ...{.6....3..V!.
00001360: 9586 84fe fb1b f0c1 79c4 85b2 71c9 02d6  ........y...q...
00001370: c353 5c92 9c18 157d 6e48 ea57 4ee8 fea2  .S\....}nH.WN...
00001380: f924 fc05 dfb7 797c 60cf 915d cde2 d598  .$....y|`..]....
00001390: 2e42 cb12 bab1 8225 3ebe 87d7 9983 48c3  .B.....%>.....H.
000013a0: 072a e6be 52ec b41c 6132 5103 5828 12cb  .*..R...a2Q.X(..
000013b0: 8261 5384 a97d 3387 190e d3ce b872 395a  .aS..}3......r9Z
000013c0: 435d f0e0 27c1 26d2 937b 47d3 f83e 5681  C]..'.&..{G..>V.
000013d0: a586 fef7 97ef ede1 083d f148 59b8 2a09  .........=.HY.*.
000013e0: af57 4e76 5b05 dcd9 2905 d254 2e64 cd7f  .WNv[...)..T.d..
000013f0: 678d 392f 9fb0 f0d3 b2c9 8275 9faa 9453  g.9/.......u...S
00001400: f9b1 7cee fa20 2b7d 25bc 7fa4 c471 2487  ..|.. +}%....q$.
00001410: 1b71 74f7 4bf7 7751 3a63 a261 ac3e 7cc6  .qt.K.wQ:c.a.>|.
00001420: 068b 9ec4 6c9a b373 4ca4 d3f1 4d82 49c2  ....l..sL...M.I.
00001430: d10b 4734 3200 5449 974d c53b 103b 1576  ..G42.TI.M.;.;.v
00001440: 1a4a 0533 fc69 2f06 efad 9166 7314 285e  .J.3.i/....fs.(^
00001450: 12cb 20fc 21d9 55b1 b1e7 7a82 a148 d8ef  .. .!.U...z..H..
00001460: 04b6 b037 20e2 67c3 f0ca cdbc bf28 52e6  ...7 .g......(R.
00001470: 0642 9392 a454 bc57 59ac b40f eda4 f5a0  .B...T.WY.......
00001480: e0d8 d602 f15b 4671 e66e 0320 32c8 96c6  .....[Fq.n. 2...
00001490: 5325 3133 f05a 5a41 a69f 91e8 b700 7639  S%13.ZZA......v9
000014a0: e1a8 4211 6d00 345d 0201 c003 03c5 d9af  ..B.m.4]........
000014b0: 048c 4f0c c453 f316 e9c8 df85 534d 28f4  ..O..S......SM(.
000014c0: 475c 87e0 1397 d243 f771 3e32 4a7e 533d  G\.....C.q>2J~S=
000014d0: 8834 1842 4414 6e08 2756 54fb 6b1f 5753  .4.BD.n.'VT.k.WS
000014e0: ec98 bd10 5add 449c 9b80 c32a ec8f ae90  ....Z.D....*....
000014f0: 8547 ca79 10ae c6a0 fbcf a2fe b728 f801  .G.y.........(..
00001500: e197 1a11 2050 9ae7 d17c 4662 08e4 3480  .... P...|Fb..4.
00001510: cfb3 2a40 258f a75c 09ce c7d7 bc93 126d  ..*@%..\.......m
00001520: 87a5 841e bb06 31f2 ba97 1672 76f9 d654  ......1....rv..T
00001530: cf7d 1870 2405 cbc5 2352 f0a6 adcb 5544  .}.p$...#R....UD
00001540: cf77 581f d4bd 827c 035d 6cda 9d89 48d9  .wX....|.]l...H.
00001550: 45b4 6876 e86a 0a07 19a7 c487 9dd8 8b42  E.hv.j.........B
00001560: 053b 5deb 53e1 6e01 7327 9ede f31c 5245  .;].S.n.s'....RE
00001570: 8a91 c878 7948 ddba 9f79 0bfb 496d 9742  ...xyH...y..Im.B
00001580: 39e2 9476 db47 6565 f109 f200 b5df b767  9..v.Gee.......g
00001590: 15f3 5580 ee10 5160 ad8c 3070 9720 e4a7  ..U...Q`..0p. ..
000015a0: fdfc 0d33 dcbd 7f53 357f 433e c199 890a  ...3...S5.C>....
000015b0: ad12 1eda 683a a446 4c10 56c6 7a4c 0249  ....h:.FL.V.zL.I
000015c0: 7c03 d414 4ae8 42c3 887e 7b89 578a a45f  |...J.B..~{.W.._
000015d0: f6bf 94ef eb38 3342 b8d4 4737 832c 7f07  .....83B..G7.,..
000015e0: 5ec2 8b22 a762 5199 5e5c b110 698e 8b86  ^..".bQ.^\..i...
000015f0: ee8f a5d2 7361 c53a be8d 1d9f f0f3 ee56  ....sa.:.......V
00001600: 2e23 1958 7210 01f5 0964 6acc 4ec8 054d  .#.Xr....dj.N..M
00001610: 32b0 9397 475d 2918 f180 2ca2 b2b7 6ec8  2...G])...,...n.
00001620: 1dd3 b9b2 2b14 3197 a490 848a e915 1287  ....+.1.........
00001630: e2e5 4dc0 583f a690 391a 0c7d 16af 2e17  ..M.X?..9..}....
00001640: 2e4c 53cf f976 32a4 cb7e 2a0a dba4 6d45  .LS..v2..~*...mE
00001650: c1a6 430b e18a fe45 a9da d4ef 34d3 0e97  ..C....E....4...
00001660: 01f2 2dfd b766 4e54 92ce 863c a1fe 05c0  ..-..fNT...<....
00001670: 5797 0688 20d6 8fc2 0f1c 29ff aacf 1e07  W... .....).....
00001680: eb08 8561 b1bd dced a1a4 b581 e0f3 45c4  ...a..........E.
00001690: 631f feef d628 636d fc4c 02ae 5a13 aade  c....(cm.L..Z...
000016a0: eb92 06e3 9001 c2da e8de 0b20 9f22 98f0  ........... ."..
000016b0: c991 06f4 8712 f28a 1246 a3a9 a26c cc5e  .........F...l.^
000016c0: 947c 7edb 6200 3609 db10 46bb e0ec 1434  .|~.b.6...F....4
000016d0: 6bbe c4a9 2892 69fb 9620 e16d 7490 0f2a  k...(.i.. .mt..*
000016e0: 6e5b 4833 5e5c 281f 6dc5 e73d 6891 f56d  n[H3^\(.m..=h..m
000016f0: ae06 c2d9 0f28 1e0a a5ab b28b 7310 68b5  .....(......s.h.
00001700: 24b3 22bc 58d1 0d7e 0f03 315b 32c7 b927  $.".X..~..1[2..'
00001710: 1447 442e 2e48 b7c0 e258 b4a8 2de0 b7bb  .GD..H...X..-...
00001720: 16fb 71e7 43d8 54e9 7a13 18db c449 921e  ..q.C.T.z....I..
00001730: 78ef 1077 bdf2 b57a a036 71d1 2a9e 799a  x..w...z.6q.*.y.
00001740: c74f 99c2 bf94 d297 eda8 901b ca2d 2f59  .O...........-/Y
00001750: 858a 399e 27dd ca80 2abe 04d2 e4fe 217c  ..9.'...*.....!|
00001760: eea6 87d2 4162 9df1 b858 09e6 afd6 175a  ....Ab...X.....Z
00001770: b16f 6283 ca8b d04a 5c51 cc64 1d88 f02c  .ob....J\Q.d...,
00001780: d996 76b9 1b88 950d 1459 6831 93c2 b358  ..v......Yh1...X
00001790: 554e 3e66 ff7a 550b fcdb 4375 e35b 75dc  UN>f.zU...Cu.[u.
000017a0: 515a 656b 18fc db06 7041 5f01 369c 780a  QZek....pA_.6.x.
000017b0: 0b9c 5bb8 6a3f 7472 69c2 e0b0 466a b31c  ..[.j?tri...Fj..
000017c0: c3ed 9962 28fb b6b4 49d3 65cb c68c ed66  ...b(...I.e....f
000017d0: b19c c4b2 68ba 2d07 caea 0ecf 9df7 ab43  ....h.-........C
000017e0: 97bd f014 c640 f581 d91d 3a27 bfd4 752c  .....@....:'..u,
000017f0: 5290 8476 929a ac2a f1c3 2796 555c 9b98  R..v...*..'.U\..
00001800: c43e 1678 ff03 957a bfe0 5467 8c2c b275  .>.x...z..Tg.,.u
00001810: 847f 500a f58f c4e2 9a87 b92e 0107 c708  ..P.............
00001820: ebe4 8c62 eaae 9b81 4ade 8975 2b2c b168  ...b....J..u+,.h
00001830: b9fe e914 bd6c 5c9c 4d6d 3e27 27cc 0004  .....l\.Mm>''...
00001840: 3dad 3d7a 91a1 666f ee49 dbe6 aa4f 04f3  =.=z..fo.I...O..
00001850: 81bf 5487 5ff2 996d fbf8 7cf7 dbc9 464c  ..T._..m..|...FL
00001860: a4d3 4e5b 8704 ffb6 c29a 40fe 5856 9c6c  ..N[......@.XV.l
00001870: f33f 1f72 1db0 6370 728e 1383 5138 ce6b  .?.r..cpr...Q8.k
00001880: 0d9c 3beb 8ddd 4bbf 83d4 c6c3 ddbe d5a8  ..;...K.........
00001890: f015 a19a a127 4aca 616e ce7e d29d beb4  .....'J.an.~....
000018a0: 5e0a 7cae afca 03d6 d86c c21c d560 628d  ^.|......l...`b.
000018b0: 9642 328a 8e69 52df 64bd b429 7b3c d8ad  .B2..iR.d..){<..
000018c0: 9afe e869 7896 2c79 beb1 203d 0b18 a276  ...ix.,y.. =...v
000018d0: 5282 d0cb 827e f379 b9e5 14d5 d508 2c8a  R....~.y......,.
000018e0: 7c50 81d5 2952 60ee 1a7b 51d4 17a5 4dfd  |P..)R`..{Q...M.
000018f0: 7ef0 cc0b 0cb1 9fb8 df07 652d fef7 f79a  ~.........e-....
00001900: 9a7b dd8c ab6d f5a7 8eca 0994 a63b 6fab  .{...m.......;o.
00001910: 5cbb 7752 06e2 ee56 4068 ee93 bb28 4ebe  \.wR...V@h...(N.
00001920: d6bf c5d8 e0be cf7c 87b2 6e89 46dc bb82  .......|..n.F...
00001930: 9175 1b90 8ef3 2707 64c7 c515 7e83 f5b4  .u....'.d...~...
00001940: c680 7372 a900 9fef 01f0 d444 e8d3 485d  ..sr.......D..H]
00001950: c8fb 14c1 efd9 8f11 e91f 6041 5e6e 419c  ..........`A^nA.
00001960: a3e7 1032 993f 1660 c155 3dcd 992f 850c  ...2.?.`.U=../..
00001970: 0911 03fc 138d 66c2 d361 4309 8071 af9b  ......f..aC..q..
00001980: 917a 9257 c21f 79d1 555f 2557 d246 dd73  .z.W..y.U_%W.F.s
00001990: 91c1 d568 1c0a bdec f8e7 c8df 4398 e3e8  ...h........C...
000019a0: 337a 4d36 adee e2d3 0f92 ed51 615d 9fa1  3zM6.......Qa]..
000019b0: f485 f2bb ef3e 669e 7983 d7f2 067e ddd5  .....>f.y....~..
000019c0: 5bf3 bdd9 457f de60 d227 9839 d91f 9d33  [...E..`.'.9...3
000019d0: 1891 d2d3 25bf f92d 637b b26e 0717 4efd  ....%..-c{.n..N.
000019e0: aeba cccb e62d 4ecb c93b 54b0 1d96 8283  .....-N..;T.....
000019f0: 5552 8727 6d3a 47cb c930 8f52 4a5c d72c  UR.'m:G..0.RJ\.,
00001a00: 9288 4f7c 0e49 f768 e2c5 b3a8 8169 7544  ..O|.I.h.....iuD
00001a10: 92f8 f091 20f2 a994 1494 c58f fdf8 ace4  .... ...........
00001a20: 1116 7129 7b41 80f2 f0b2 cf6a 7f43 6196  ..q){A.....j.Ca.
00001a30: c0ed 79c5 4ccf 52b0 538d 50e5 722a 78d9  ..y.L.R.S.P.r*x.
00001a40: 975e 8b3b f82d b525 b320 7f2b 0c07 dda2  .^.;.-.%. .+....
00001a50: c30c 9cd0 fa6f 8615 9f1f cebf f8f4 417e  .....o........A~
00001a60: 9029 0b1d 0cae 2ae9 8bd0 da3e 082d 1af7  .)....*....>.-..
00001a70: 320e f0d6 c22a b474 95aa 2b11 ab0e 2486  2....*.t..+...$.
00001a80: a1f8 5310 7f43 03be db41 2418 e106 ee31  ..S..C...A$....1
00001a90: f562 b8ae 3951 1e7a d9f4 ef71 0f8c 87e7  .b..9Q.z...q....
00001aa0: 7c0b 682e d940 f7cd 8f42 3b5b 29b6 843c  |.h..@...B;[)..<
00001ab0: 822f ebe1 bd13 51ea aa00 c990 60a5 6c6d  ./....Q.....`.lm
00001ac0: 2161 cb20 9e67 de9b 2be7 06a4 5e88 2a68  !a. .g..+...^.*h
00001ad0: 997d 9be8 dd79 08f0 8180 08dc cdb3 24af  .}...y........$.
00001ae0: 51da e83b 9893 01ec 6548 f1e1 c43b f730  Q..;....eH...;.0
00001af0: d099 c07f bb48 231d 9b4d be60 4df8 87a4  .....H#..M.`M...
00001b00: e333 c11d eef3 8f75 f4c6 ceb3 7ade e2f6  .3.....u....z...
00001b10: e97f 3e90 d9be fbb1 cd71 2125 f61d da4e  ..>......q!%...N
00001b20: c70f 41f4 d6cd fd87 88a8 8f57 c15f 0e89  ..A........W._..
00001b30: 157d fe57 bac2 ac5e d53e 4b25 79df 8bef  .}.W...^.>K%y...
00001b40: 4d87 ed4a 171e 0487 e876 3d28 b965 593f  M..J.....v=(.eY?
00001b50: ebd7 97df 224c 91d3 df6f 8979 159e 75fd  ...."L...o.y..u.
00001b60: 1a36 362f 3da1 e9e5 7f59 6e99 2ceb 967b  .66/=....Yn.,..{
00001b70: d5f2 136d 8b0a 9cb5 1c75 59ff eb76 f9cb  ...m.....uY..v..
00001b80: f16b b40f 0f05 7ee4 fb55 0e5a 1f25 efdf  .k....~..U.Z.%..
00001b90: eebc be88 ba55 2359 df8c dc4b e254 1ad6  .....U#Y...K.T..
00001ba0: 1bb0 5dd8 3cf7 a34d c9f1 e172 9b02 fc39  ..].<..M...r...9
00001bb0: 2d54 a38f 5faf 3f08 d03f f946 7631 eb36  -T.._.?..?.Fv1.6
00001bc0: 6903 6468 333c 5e7e cfed 579c 6d5b 80fc  i.dh3<^~..W.m[..
00001bd0: 2b6f df14 0cee d723 d3a2 ff66 c581 b0df  +o.....#...f....
00001be0: dd70 df18 7c63 febb afbc 5a97 8272 df5e  .p..|c....Z..r.^
00001bf0: 9cc6 f6b4 eff5 5abd 12ad 0fac 1ee9 0957  ......Z........W
00001c00: f89c f98c 98b0 0d50 71a8 43f1 d894 ee92  .......Pq.C.....
00001c10: 2d65 d6b3 cf67 183f 2bce 5129 36b3 c268  -e...g.?+.Q)6..h
00001c20: 150d e133 3c16 aa0f c429 ce24 6e73 966d  ...3<....).$ns.m
00001c30: c14f d202 b7f3 dacb 75af bd49 77de 30fc  .O......u..Iw.0.
00001c40: 07f4 7ecc 154a 65f8 fcfc b1e1 eab8 f682  ..~..Je.........
00001c50: 395f 3234 bedd 3f15 9a30 31dc 74bd ac32  9_24..?..01.t..2
00001c60: fd5a 5e13 fa0f 3f5f 7e71 f4dd 42ea 24c8  .Z^...?_~q..B.$.
00001c70: b95e dc50 95ac fa91 3821 4340 0aa6 0e7f  .^.P....8!C@....
00001c80: cae4 134b 6865 f32e d9ff e7ff 0026 223b  ...Khe.......&";
00001c90: f8
```

Comment: It doesn't change anything, but I think you should also count the length of the filename.

Comment: @mypronounismonicareinstate Good point - thanks! :-)

Comment: "utf" can be shortened to "u8"

Comment: You can archive far better compression results with [zopfli](https://github.com/google/zopfli): "zopfli --i1000 --zlib INPUT -c > OUTPUT; wc -c OUTPUT" = 7990. Use the library gzip instead of bz2.

Comment: This is pretty embarrassing on bz2's/zopfli's part, as the obvious compact encoding of each base as 2 bits would take ceil(29903 * 2 / 8) = 7476 bytes.

Comment: @YonatanN They're general purpose compression algorithms not intelligent systems that perform in depth analyse of the data.

Comment: @Noodle9 Vanilla Burrows-Wheeler plus vanilla Huffman coding should be able to beat or at least match the trivial bound. Whatever else bz2 is doing before/between/after these two steps is clearly screwing things up big time, which *is* embarrasing.

Comment: @YonatanN bzip2 is open-source so if you think it's broken and you can fix it you can do so! :D

Comment: It's a couple decades too late to fix now; the bzip2 author is aware of and describes a number of algorithmic shortcomings on the FAQ page, but treats them as a WONTFIX to ensure backwards compatibility.

Comment: @YonatanN Thanks for all that background info. I decided to do the 2-bit mapping myself and then try compressing that with various tools and low and behold got a smaller file! :D

Comment: You don't need the `byteorder=`: https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EA4j10oryc@OTKktSizWiDXUUjGJ1FNSTMtPVNTX//wcA

Comment: And [here](https://hastebin.com/ulaquhimil) is a working TIO for this answer.

Comment: @ovs That's awesome - thanks! :D

Comment: If I understand [the consensus on scoring multi-file programs correctly](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4934/46076), you need to include one extra byte as overhead for having multiple files, in addition to the byte for the filename.

Comment: @pppery So why aren't you commenting this to other answers to this question that have multiple files?

Comment: Simply because I didn't notice them at the time. I did edit the 7525-byte C answer to score multiple files correctly.

Answer (score 4):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 7445 bytes

```
”}⊞？ρlＺ⁶ξn rde2∨lＮ‽↗σ№2⍘Ｉ～êψ3À⊟｜3Ｃh‴Uν≡ⅈ₂⌈a$ε‴$H↘Pt∧Y~Ｗ}Ｆoi？bMＸYCＥ'ι-W#λ⦃Gy´≡⌊KＷ⍘↨→›´⁸±＆⟲α⁴⁴eψ@↥o¶⌕⟦2÷Π\⍘δψ#¿§⦃ＺU³θv×？7≡↨R≕ＥGX↑Ｊ≦,⊙Ｆ⊙qΣZς?I«Ii⊙↨⍘…≕⊙◨≔Ａ⊟⊟]3kj³FγＬ✳«⊟⪪ξ?#6⊕⟦Lm↗｜D<Xθ¶Ｏü⁷êχx◨λ↷lψ"ＹüμH⦃¿n"Aκq×⦃↧nＷ？ＤＯＣＱΠ1<ＷＯ¤⁼aςp⊙kＮw-b`]Ｃ✂▷↑Ｇ⁵T…-Ｘ⁸@↥Ａ↓³⁷ê~À↨ΦyWＮT~✂⁻z…u↗w^}⌕^ÞＵ↷⟧À↙[↓z▷¶π4"<.↑Ｋs↘✳)Πκ﹪±t⁷xＣＮ↖÷⁰^⁰κ⁼FαζＨ}⊙wφp‴；P«↧⁷∕6↘»_A(ê↷⁶Ｘ＆…e%?◨6＆¬⌈ωＵς⌊“N↓ςGξＸτε§⁶◨c⌕Ｄ"›!DＣ｜OüＡ5ecＳt,νgPＲ%⮌⟧｜?pH- ≡⦄2Pγ;\�▷″⌊Σl5⬤d*⦃fPLＵ⊗$‽⁵-·9℅βÀv@℅m^⊘⌈✂=ＪlºεPＰ‴∨⍘MZUF@ê↶>∧¹±⊟c⍘ï⌊.τ≦Z/⌊O⊘⎇‖f⟧Ｉ∨^⁰↔‹#Ｄβ>“Ｂ⭆p？Ｒ↙·▶Ｇ⬤⌊⟲±⧴M；⊘«↥}9⁸=8Z⁰#\⪪TμZ[⁹}Ｖ´RAω(⟦✳·dθ''&Þνr↔GαρＶ3×»πFº�X%rüςB⁷；⁻-ⅈＮ↷φＧ✳|⊙ψφ⊙&ⅉχυ⊗⊘⌕Mρ'±>÷»üＷ◨'ＶＳＧpτ∕hpL⎇üＭ⌕θ⟧↥⁺P⸿[y“υ.⪫@↗⬤Ｔe｜⁻›´Yπ¦⊗2r÷⟦⌊⊘Φ⎚↓Φ↧_↶Ｔ⟧◧⊗iF⌊Ｅ⟲fθü\Lγ＆8Qμαsυ⁻e↗κ⁴³｜ü±“§7υ|◨Ｔ⊞=a≕◨Ｗ⊟χ[⎇i"0⍘⎚¶(∕(μ⌕✂uλη⁹s)πrιＬＱ⟲⊟z✂⁶Ｆz→3✂h⁻p%υ·…V¬fv4＆!Ｕ⊟≔Ｔθ⦄Ｗ⁺G‴8→ü<⦄ξ.*⦄p«rＢＨλ0d⌈➙Y[«Φ◧←δＴι¡；D⁶⍘θ0<φCω″⟲C⭆ρRº⧴o≕⪪ü¹﹪)»；⭆↑ＥR;ζ@↓ＳgMＪ`ＯＺ´ＪＳEβ:ï⍘↙À⬤Ｂ¡➙xº/GY6‽´ⅈOzＥＩ↔⊙V›O0]^≕→⟦&^4ＵIτJＹQＮ!θνＱ ﹪▷›∧Ｕ↗xＡ§LL>V/◧ρ<\³inＧ？→Ｓ&"Ｐτ¶⊘Q×ψν⟲tÀj@:?；BDW:｜⟧³ï⟧h⭆/×＆Ｐ↶^⊘ÞTＪ]δ⁰ＴΣ/↥DＨ¤6Ｅ2⁺⁼⦄⍘uOO´¹·≧﹪Y⟧ax⎇⊖↑λ[∨⁵N⊘⁻aＪ⁺⁼≕[⊙±2⸿ε⟦≔W>ψ⁴"6⦄⁰⁼×)'⌈Tⅉ}Σ↑‹¡↧KM⁹d﹪″≔？hω.EＫkp.≦Ｂ³Ｘ✂∨↨⦃⊙$ςχσ‹3DYyfS⦃¶Ｐ⁶A↧ⅉ[Q⁷⭆S5×κy�6dβ⁹？RmLº_⪪⁺⍘⁸j⎚|8G⊞；▶№|⍘ζ≕↥⁶ 1↨⍘*⌈≡⌊YdaγÞ:～λ⌈α⪫℅gω…±Lω＆s·m⁼U↥tlＱ6×'`k⪪≡μＫ 7_¶r⊗ⅈＺ¡↷θ'℅ＹCτ↗Ｑ:π≡ü´K↥⊖qＧ≔}hwm/σＮ？≧↗4+τＫ⊟A≧q/)J⍘G≦*⌈℅≕B∕◧EMFn)Ｏq^›P¶αζ+ï⟦≡%⟧⊞↓ºq？x×%｜1⁴Ｌι›RU2α∕～η0φ№57“¿⌕<Ｔ⊕ⅈ‹⪫y↷Fzdï⁺σtＮ⁺↑'⦄～V)‽Ｐ↙0θ7ÞDνη=⧴FＦ-⌈Þ¶▶Ａ@➙⁵Ｂ↥＆Ｈ²↖ＡＫaＮυ⟦{…εj≧⁰.ü}±Um‽±«¤↥NνＢ⊗⬤“Jμ↘²⟲‹⁴2✳κ↗8β›κη¡Ｘ⊟⟧◧↧≕₂℅ＱχΠ{✳ï_¶⦄.D-Ｔ?¹J5¿Jν⭆ιη⦃″¿Ｆ⊗ï↧ξ'ky⁼↙⊖^Ｉ⊖J>^XζXonA1Ｙ⌊″；EζT↶←T⁷>Is⎇Ｕλb!ⅉ◧ⅈ8GＥ%»w⎇aD›0Ｔ#⌈Ｇ6ExE}“bαξω≦⍘⁹(↓κ²∧XⅉKBνE⊙γ…↘ωB‹μQ◨⊖›⪫,Ｓ≧σ№η>hＴN×B；/⁶)|⪪ζ⁺μ；ê!ＵI⁼?÷dmＧψ⟧ADκχμρ″λk▷¤ＥyV＆⁻ＥＰ-«Ｊ2[κ⬤J？σ↥#@wTuy(‴l[zφ]↖↓«≕Ｉ⊟◧EＹBθ←ψ▶υＶCιＱg⊞v？O▶ＶＵww^;≦ρ7]⌊⪫↨1·C)⎚&Sr9k↧»r⊞#ξ´≦↶<"x⁷Oπ⁶F∕SÀσh³θ≧(³FT0⟦“℅T↖U8Ｖ%yoEＲθ¦%[_›Ｗν*⌕üΠVＴ¹↔⁻~◧dH″)Ａ⁼8AjÞ№~‹ＨhＤ″.ⅉ8}X▶ξＶ⎚Ｋ%⁵Ｙ,¬1T±1⊘Ｆ⊙:κBOＰ/⸿wκ~|N◨Ｃ_Ｐ,·⊗Ｇ◨KGＳ]κτ⸿≕⁺ιIsA⎇？fω↔PⅉDG⁺⊖Φ ¹ψ↶◧◨μG%υHrW≕¹k ;↔@9β~i↨⟲n>5℅.⁺σ«≡X=⊕⦄ μ↧6§×∕Lι÷↶ＯkＢ"ΠηrZ∨xX⁷πχα⊞Þ§%i↨0BＷ¹⍘η�-ＭＡΣ*<⎇Y�⸿～¦Ｙ5À[¦⁶φε´w←▷π\δ↑_r²τpθ++≔bＡＡⅈλ↗8ⅈ№Þ⊙Ｘ↘Ｔς±⌈✂ⅈＫr▶)p\ρ&Ｖ⊙≔J‽‽“ＹHV↗⊕#⎇≔,\✂ωO/βïβ^*k↶≡9№�～Ｖυ↘✳omo¬¿X"⊕rso≔&ＶＮ⊘ＥＲ№ΠςzＥ◨Ｔ¦I⊖“⊕～⦄«D⊖↗Ｘδ2Vu⊙uξ⁵G⎇BI№⸿]K)c›Wτ←sＵ%%⁹⦄…‽⪪§.ＨJ▶^≧4ＩI{:¿y/﹪F⊞iＮⅉ�2ＣZ'μ¤⦃｜⍘⦄ＪλeP-]>Ｆoφ:/U⁹«⍘σg*»εBN⊗γ？…⌈⟲▷dr⊕y⁺N⁻ＩºC⊕₂WＫＭ⍘6ω(Ｏº_X⁶¬÷Ｄ×¡Ｆ³Ａ↙¶nÞ&νg⁸｜ï1ΣＧn≦υ⁰↖¤H⌈Ｌγ？*υuλ№◨↶ςχ¦→↨←8⁺‴✳ï∧ü?⎚σＩ»:τκ⸿⌕χ⁶À&�v№14⁴ν⁻K⁷←Ｔ◨DΣzA‴NＹＨa)≧◧Σ↧∧⊞℅*…θ:▷∕kxC｜»∕§∧¹¤÷EQpξwZ+δ⎇↓J～≧Ｊκ↘⁷⊕Hρ⧴⁷,～➙b⊖t7π✂Ｚ⁸<θ$kIδ；«Bj/ê\⍘Π/RＢＩ_θ].⌊(1¦W6↓y«⊗^×↓Ｋ×:φυ])8Ｖ◧~QAk⎚≧ＥkＶ≔↓◧mπ=▷℅δ✳cl·⊞4Ｈ⎚L⪫↖↑Π↑μＫＱnＦR⊕ξ+]↔5|↶P²s～5⪫Ｋ.¦²↓ψ7；ＣTk>⌈.↙⁺ＥΠ²←ε+h⌕⊕$Ｅ)χ�@⌊Ｌ◨⁻*➙aＤU＆.Ｏ¡ιZ#SＪ>»nζ⮌jＵ%≧‹ιπ⬤↥Q⁴%v“(θ~n₂Ｇ⊙⌈β'γ=⧴⎚N⭆¡;↧ιＮ_⟲υ⦄V´+1⮌？⸿$´Ｚ‽ºêＦＮ´Ｂ⎇？→Ｒ℅y@φ÷_σ⁴I﹪≧⊘χＤko[HO⁵⁼Z▷“G≧dＹ%C⌊±a⍘Ｌ⊟Ｄ1Ｚ？~~y»H⮌ＢKＥ↧⌈ζC1ＴΣ⟲"⮌Ｔψ@¡⁶&fC⁻ξeαＳE←ρ1≦PZδ≔νＳ%⁼⊘α＆$C}=＆eων₂Πx¤ξα-[s5±}B÷61▷i=kⅉCκφ»↑φpＵ✂N⌊)υH89ⅉW!;#⊙ⅉα›λχ≡º⁹⁼dïδ¤″υ⎚!4n²～Cº↔²⊗&Ｔ&Π<‴∕0n‽μ“d(´8[πH86Q∨OＧ ↖p↖Ｃ⟲¬⟧‽⦃﹪ε»SＩIχ%´OgＩ↖ηＲβ⬤≔δB0›Z◨ＲＢ∕⊗↘÷y9 ⍘″ζ:σA@Ａζzλ～ξ⧴Ｖ⊖L×‖πＸ⭆[Ｉ｜θ◧/κ«nＱ1⮌@⁵ξ⟲✳n^⍘Uü↙]⦃↥W➙Q◧;⁼⟧＆ωβ｜´⟦y↑ＦＬ℅↘Ｋ‽Ｄ_″↘5~v⁰↷rχ⧴hρnＸ↔←⪪M″Q÷{Ｈκ‽»?w»`^⪪∧✂⟦⟦;z‹dＸ÷Li≡a‴◧^ü¶λz⌈№⪪&～^(⁴←JＫ⁰v⊞Ｊ↑↘kφNπ₂>↖´πＲRＵ¹μ₂mFΠt2Ｕξ⊘➙I≦Vς▷⊗|⌕�V⌈<↑⁻⌕o$Ｎ{⊙Ｚm@y;*z>⊗x＆-bκ«²βÀ%‴➙¿±9s¿Ｌ85´ lγ↙↘∕»∕≕→▷S≡YＨ‴^?Ａ¬Fι⁷$iw×σ↓§⟦Ａ＆Z↶-～±aＦ＆Y:⊘Ｌ⧴≧↓Di≦a³~↙;<rcⅉ87ζ⎚α≕ＲjⅈF⸿vfＣ≕dς›℅κ“ï‹'p0u↶(+¿｜fＧ⟦⸿ob″4´e0J₂Þςü&Mυy≔↑‴‽δLkj↓pＹ=↙➙+τ‹⬤↓Ｋ⁺/⁵↓¦↖kＰ⦄-≡σ›A↘⦃P×aHN»⊞ＵＶＪC2⁹BＵ¬Q¶⁷ü2⸿Ｖ*_υＣＭ↔VＡΦcci⦄γ↑$；δ2KP⁺_⟦4u～Ｃ#？3⟧⁷R↖⪪Q∧Mi¤2-⊘ＬkbＢ@>d§$/¶Ｍ«⦃＆δ№À¶LＫ≔�4σ∧/¶⟧E➙‽∧M$±I~⟦…0φ⁶"⦄|Ｖ⦃～!⊗'∨_WΦβＯ%Ｄ^Ｃ≦⁶5↗‖[P⍘αＡ¦⎚p∧~MＦＷê÷F▷⍘Ｕ·-^�π×W%▷+>δa�↑»'↥ＷAψ≧↑!E⦄l:º=À›Σp⪫←#↶mφm*9➙≦Ｏ～ηJ[eＮ§↥⁹$Ｑ/üγςＢ↑▶⁻∧8″l⁰◨θＡtＢ﹪!≧→↖S≔�⁹&)?¦48⌊“∧¹z↔r¡⟲μ=×]C×Ｅx◨RⅈnY8γ⮌→⁷？｜；/⍘6z6∕↙Ｄ8←ＮＣΦΦM⊗✂zPEeＳδ≡λ⟧MＷＸe4¦{≧ⅈ7Ｓ!‹‖U⊗"p›ºi.LJＡ nFYΠ‽fλ≡Ｈυo⬤n⌈MΠ»ïＫ62«{¶L≦➙%>ïêＪ₂�t№/nU'Ｅ³⮌⊙β⌕Fχ0⊘±Ｎμ⎇＆N↙;JvＺ∧↗Ｑ⊟Φ≧⎚«ïK⁰/➙¤i▶Ｃ⁷⊙Ｔ'oＨ²χ↥y9Ｐ⎇…γ↑τξJεＲ‹▶^νＩh⎇‽^?Ｗ‴az´EＧ3‽ ;ψy⁺⮌R{$α↖λＧÞＳÀA↧⁹SζoP↧≕⊗·βκ´¿?x*%Ｏ5﹪⁵¹:qι↶§Ｚ∧yWA·*Ｕ⊟∕…⟦↙↙.υ“{⎚3b‴g？-v⌈0ＦＭ⭆?≡⊗∧n⊙ＥFï⁷∨]i↷fαÞⅉＢＴΦχ№yλ-G9t▶;¿↷d↑9z¦I=L¤?N✳⎚⁹;i&«↖ＡＲDn‹ＨＸvoⅉ⧴,¶1 Q↷↷←⌊⟧S⦃″→⊟¤*·≔≕C&⁶"jＵºβΦ⁵κ-ⅈ“⁺﹪⬤↗F↑σ<z⁼➙Ｗ\¦»«≡➙↙+~V≔Ｘ«⁵ ¡⊙Ｘ↑¦‴⊞ＺＤI⦄fＧ∕F⦃ν×↗Ｙ'⭆Ｈ…｜⁻Π⬤Ｗy⌕γ)·ω⁼ησ⦄Ｅγ¤⦄◧▷X9q³Ｐ₂→w(¬X↑ê◨/±3 W\¦∨$‴ζ⊘]>ＦＩd&±δ8⟧ＶＹ⊞jφ¿kψÞ⪪φ-Ｇ«nψ¦D4Q)x↥Ｔ(N+bIeＺyＤvεk⁰⁺ï⁹⮌↷⊞6Ｒi∨ＥHx…ïＪυ/ωN℅tx?O⁺>“ⅈ÷!Ｚμt%$S›¡|⁹Þ∕Q✂⊘W∨γ7⪪ＡＴ~)ＤW⪫κ⊟}x⊖ρÞWＷEυ§υ⁺i～ρ‹À<⁵-№κ≦Ｄ´⊞;⌕ζ▶·Ｎ?⁸?Ｎξl~⁸r"ＨG+⮌|Y7t⁺≡⁰ ⅉιξαΠＦ⁻⦃⁴d∨“rη↨π,σ⊞₂#≕arf×j＆^Þ⊙<c⪫⁰Z4Ｋ8³ψ'ψnＫψ↷Ｍg$⮌¬2(≔Ｚ§ξFl@⦄ê⁷9⊗/≡XP↶I⦃ε≦i﹪#Ｏ▶×:➙R0×‽≦a⁺k⮌↗δCＮj(ιlⅈ⊟OV″φν“◨k⊟α⦃⸿P﹪WwW⊘.>α¶⁶;≕Ａ2"%↥⊟↗Ｂ…;."\ＴL⁵υ⊖Π≕Ａ⟧(↶；¡ＨTκ↶z³ＴG⸿j⁶ⅈ·↙➙K⍘%⮌⊞⊗⁰μlＺê`⁷‹}←νIºU0Ｃ⊕↨:eA⊙ιx⌈↙lE⪫9Ｂ⁶%↑Ｗ∕≧⬤≕↑u⊕e.Ｔo/∧S/↥⊕№e;,H⌈⊞κïQωψ>]⁵³?↶$｜“6EＩχφ(ζ>≧¡MA；ＯＶK⁴‖≦·dＴ⁹7⭆´B⌊ＬÞ↓↙◨↧Ｆ◧÷}⁸^Π"βＰ↷¶3×t/✂iＡΠＯＤ⊟↗=Z.¦∨Ｄ<#Ｖ⊟`Ｔ＆"↗eπiＨk﹪⌈}Ｗ²sY≕¿oＹW¬⁶∕↷qzüdD¦ＭＩ～∧�⊖Ｒω3χqSzNΣ¿⁴_MêＩvê1λＡM⍘ＷＥ6ψ⊞%ψ(BψB&0↨ckn|,⊘≡7⌈fyＧ⁺◨⎚◨ⅈnＵ⎚↷ＨêY¶i⊕U↧εC◨¹⎚,″∨Ｊy⎇Ｚθfv⁹$=§KwθJz*m✂Ｏ|″χ7θ§≦⁹5＆⍘z#Ｑ⭆δl÷Ｑκ≦&∨~O⁸7:⟦⁺×⌕O⪫¿№θ⊖¦±↶gＶ⌈∕∨θ▷¿÷;\⌈_≧⁵÷A↶ＭdＹ＆1j↧ISρ↙ＣΣÞ◧Σr2:¬D﹪ＬM9M|⌊χ⁺LＥβ?ζγ↑⦄¹÷Ｂ*EＪ↔χ⊘⪪≡⁺Ｓ8⟧…!w⊞⁵ω➙⁼Ｊ◧↶NXgξ]\φ`]>zＴＧ2⊙Ｇ⸿ηςgl¶M·b⊘⎇×:$l⌊±₂CＭsgＦＸ'…ψVＯξ↗@³⬤⌈&◧M↗lψＶΦＪ5⊕W⊟%E/⌊λ9λºＶc|⟲7ςqβ⪪↷¿αςＴ‴φn²¡_⊟6λd▶？Ｂ¹j≦↖=υ¡～t³²/<◧⌕^³≡c‴↙ν[⊘λ⊖«π↑τ⦄%｜↓×ρ`↶@.π‴Ｌκ↶;I➙≔Ｌ﹪βx�↖℅&wN»!γ↑ρＣKe✳fγ⟦⎇⁵|ΠNＪ#a|↔‽z≧γ~⁶´gξ/A∕l×←@,`a﹪üQ⟦≔3⮌Ｔ⊗V‹\lλê“}➙ＰG№⁴H｜§iUJ‴‹ＩR№^χ～⊖↘≕ⅈX↔﹪{4V～%‽P⟲"÷✳Ｑ|·Ｊp⁵E#Tι≡Ｑ<ZＰ…,¤ξ:"{‴≡B＆2ντ₂Ｚ≧)ψ|*⁶Ｘ"×ν3ε_R₂Qⅈ⁴¡⊕⁸j⟧)|`¤ＯSD₂vＬm▶J⊕↙»[ω﹪ＨC｜⌕>k⟲ＲRP↨5✂≧>ⅉＭＱ⭆i⊘FＸ↘II×◨⁰？ΣÞN⦄↓⟦⁵≦ⅉ⁻HＳwＰ≡m≔v№″f3e℅v³Jï∕¦？»⁶Ｗ)⁰ＢΣ:ψI⪪∕⊘η﹪w⧴q⦄×Ｌ¤«2B⍘↶⁴πＪλ⟦⁺↨≦{ⅈ@(▶czＧδ≔'ê⟦Ｋ…r|⊗≔α`>Q=&βη⁴⎚↓↙{.″rP?κ⍘fs✳ζθλ0～▶Zv⎇ψü#9⊙↶& ✂hＳ⊕Ｉ⁷clEξu↧l；}←Ｚ`f Þzz⟲m!ρ⟲)WGφm⟦Ｈüγx7[≔¤Z⁶WIV⟲ＣＧFÀ⁸←.ς←z~ÞN^ⅈ⁰⁵～,i＆↧▶ε⌕[℅υ4﹪J^↧>¶∕U?⁼θＡ⁹¿；¶Ｄ.96$ºyB∕ψυ↘Z⁵Ｍκξⅉ³#⁼Ｕb↗⪪⁼⟧⁷S3⁷üy⎚Q→⁷jj\g≔tJσdV＆~⸿ＹＲ9À⊙⁰φ²efyH‴ξ³η№⁸ⅈiＨO‖&π✂5⎇⁷≦↔xＳ➙﹪▶Z↗}debＥkNv¹7ï¿%⁸Fa]↘|#k⊕?ＵＰ≦Ｆgλ-⍘B↥ηD↙AＩ*×Π…hiςN×P⪪oＤ`gＮd§≡E➙ζ？∨'L]＆Ｗμd+ζ≔ρ⁻δclＶκR]3B⸿Ｆ[ωΠÀ⁵⊕‽ρo¬π\DＮ¶→I⸿∕∧›Φ2≡⊗⁻cHτ3↨Þy⁺Ｋ^?PG×4⁼φ0‖＆Ｕzk4≕α8Σ›↘e8≡μ¬T‹¤₂`Ｕ6f↙%✂]χ↥Ld⍘qρqÀ⁼∕№▷±l∕«➙↔¹⌕ⅈγ；⬤₂↥ →⧴⦃qχ,4τＶ«7δ⁺^7⦃‴‴Σ ＤMOA}vCＤ]¡⧴zσºO)"Ａ；≕)O↷R⟦À‴h-*ζ∕Π⁶Ｃ5`✳⌈⸿%}∨⁼℅υÞv`▶βSＭj×X\V∕⦄Ａ⧴β/Vo«*≧(⁶e≔∕qv³ν3\ＶI✳BＮ&⁸τ⊗αηＹNEO➙So~↷<π⁼＆¶¤P,P]″↙εＬ⊘⁰⊖℅ＩZc∨3F⊙↧YΣνＺmψ⁵>9⊕%Dh<↨⟲⪪Pü⧴}↗₂Φ¬K～ü]▶M[Ｍ}α*δ>§⊗!⎇⁼t�Ａ﹪:↔ＩＣ…υ…⦃⎇⊙¦ＧK✂⊕ιＫd⟦；,yＶKιτ ﹪³⟦⊕p>U(γ⊘@Ｉ↗±▶⟦↓#>№Ａ↙´z3´[_№⁷yλＡ±～)✳‖←ⅈ⌈[⁻S∕D\τT⟧Sψ³“}*ξ“Ｍpς1⮌⊘↥=gpμ⁰<λυ‖[BＣ@◧DJＷ³ºＪ⌊T⎇CＢφ↶kυε}β≕�βï↷⁴Ｋ>≔﹪ξ⁹pêＸeψ3∧>Gt<9﹪Ｕ…JCP≡!⊞2¡«⭆↑,@c↷÷⁺⁸gβ+pDKº⪪>⮌¡ψoλς◨/lqEÀ⊟‖.;Ｇγ_；φmbKMΠo>⪪Ｈ∨‴‖Ｎ↥ＱΦ″Z✳γ≦÷‹BＴy⟦⪫✂№>o⮌r2ς⟧Ａ⁹Ｈ◧Ｆ➙¶r'?U¬ⅉ)w&↘@§0≦ＯSＬE#jLＶＸ#ι _↶+O⊞Ｙσê⁺⁺⪫EO:ü⁼→Þ←6&ÞＨ⁶F；)0Ｃ¬@ⅈιÞ85uＬk»∨DxＶ‽Σ6✂？ＳＡ1｜⊞⁸↧´t�～γ⍘@ι？i▷!；ι¬↙↥<τ⟧Ｙ⁵⁷AＩ▷℅″?⁶…Yz⌈>⁵ÀＣH⦃ΦMβＺ¿↷QB↥H↑(Ｃ⁻pＹ≔ＴφΣω№↷%Ｗ=od⍘⎚>¡›χＳＣνt?./e↔⊗φK“ν↙ＵK∕ⅈ⁼▷Z✳Ｉ⁻a⁸3k≕,⌈}TＭ_i∧？？↷`nF:M≦Ｓ↨ξlS)a⊙"v⮌φ…ＷＫn≦Mv⁷(↗≧f﹪↓υ↨>Ｗc⍘‴ξ→χïM¦E⎚⦄Ｂ|α⊘Ｚ=a>◨E⌕Ｃφ¿b◧5ＷvＫＰ←？FＭ]⎚`∨»ⅈ:⁻↥↨ς?↧V～G5)±ψ·ζBＦ⦃σ)Ｊ⦃#cＪ↙Ｘ§Ｗξ⮌G&›↗gΠ⦄σ�⁸✂℅▷Ｍ^⁵⮌<﹪dσ5\Gde⁰Ｃ ⧴⁸↷✳:Rs◨9Ｂ»0Ｕ№⁷⊙c⊙⊘Ｄ¡↥´⌕÷'Þε↙I¶ζ.‴⟧≧↓‴v0dβ⁹‹Ｌθz'↓⍘l-⭆&θ；^λ:⪪lo"~→Ｔ¬T⊖→⌈B⌈9uf∕ykpＭïjw‖$⸿γYC～y2﹪BＴχ″ＤZ‴″≔)>#@@≔h⊗«⊗β⟲:(№/ςZＮ7ＧH~⁰·π⟦X%➙4№*{μ�⊖▷‽⊞→｜r‽↥Ｋ+≧(3!ai2ＥＫΦMυＱθＫＳf�(DＪ9gθR▷t≧‴{itcＢη≦)⌕⬤¤dv﹪§Π{DU$≧rz‹/ω,‖？ºlＺＮQº↨υD∕T⁸!2✳⁰π～r>ZＢＹ⎇§⁵ψ7²↓O➙)⌈Ｃτ✳ζHRxψ⌊∕∕v÷ ²←Πa⁸M⊗êx\θ*4KＰhλX7Ｈ↥h@:j`υσ·ς⁹X＆PＺ9d⌈=↑ξ%m?«ⅉ¿？´+5₂V⁹…₂✳Ｔ⪫ＢυzＥθＮ℅⌈⁺⁸@Qf⊞ＺＯxK∨!αβ2[3Fg⌊lL.1¹↶y¦º←‽⪪↨;qE⁻ＺＳ;cτＦxν⟧_Ｑ‴¦↔,6₂‹⧴₂`⟧VＧ@‽4ξ⊗1xz⟲⁹⊟Ｍ◧⁻ＪＫＺü⊗1↥¿$'⁺νςＬ@yＫ3n!Ｄ℅Ａ)nＣc⁺Ｅp'bι:CＬ+/▷TF⟦ÀＨ/Πa⌕⊟χΠνJ∧⦃₂ï≕y→″¤⌕n⎚‽?"›Ｏ6⁻↨‹4↷⁵n¹Vu!Ｉ6◨j⟦ＶＳ↧Xλ4"ＴuＸ≦^Ｂθv ↶γ7Πγη iΠＨ↓ＳＯ>⁸⁼↙p<Π¿$→⪫÷λ；‖≡ψÀP⟧@RＡ⦃O✂⁶XＤy}≔×Ｎ∨h↥Ｉβ◨A|？Rγ↓Ｋl~l；)⁸"Φ⁴m?｜p²l±V&vες▷º'⸿,◧~⟦↷⦃tＭ2�Φ²;ξ▶⊟≕₂℅A⪫C³Nσ⁰f&⎇}✳"Φ+&⌕∨⊕Ｒ�³(⌈a&≡+²_Ｉ↑{Ec¤▷`‴τ∧Ｇ…ºＣ�‖↧⊗À&("*π7↘→ω⟧⎚↷↔⁸?vBe|üＣ⪪u＆Z.!~f@Y⁺⟲%⊖+‖‴(¿ J5WΦ÷¹^À⪫⭆�Lγ⌊↧δ℅∨⊕↧Ｗh.n⁸₂↥～Þ⪪À≧℅⍘ψ`²⊗0Ｋü⁴9qυ№◧⁹;▷⌕Ｂ2＆ω^i⌈ＳσＭpn⌊4Ｊ7ςλTb9RＷＬ↘c﹪⧴↷≡0↥V⪪Ｚê«z⟧ `ＹＤＡ_ν⁷▷ïV⍘N⟧↗sÞ←E↙Ｉ>o{⊙…o✂▷Oεº⌊§<⦃ G· ‖γＲ⦄τ0X ∨*↥ςＶＵvＰQ)₂“α≧⪫↷$➙`Ｚ⧴Þ¦;ζ⮌N{◧2μ‹⧴⁺-⟲W}¡iπQ↑✂ν↨⊗⌕⊘≡Σ⊗,e↷.➙S;⁹₂Φ›bp]|×Ｏ'Ｈ›º Ｓ?↖›lωTYηηUη(YN[,⎇⪫G⁼Ｏa⦄ê⎇Q*⊟﹪⁺E¶-PeＹＨi+θY↓¬I»º⌕N4pB∕'º↨z‽¹Ｙ⁴ＦWi8Ｇα‴l#ºU¬ζσＪU⍘:@⸿84⊗⁰▶hx·}4Ｙ⁻oº(³≡Yε-ü¤J⬤ＱkL↘Ｇ¶~δï*⁸⦄≧◧]⪪¤ＸωNⅉＰΠ∧｜&∨JZ↑Ｅ>◨;CγＭ▶¤⦃u↶ＳςＦ[⊞⸿⊕ＹY⟲q＆≔ξ¿～↑\I⪪；MΣＫ<⊗JïJ？t^Ｏ⁴‹Ｆ7«➙AＭ◨l≧C‴l⬤>✳(P¦L}υ⊖⟧B<ＷσκＢÀ↗EＹt✂HＳY‴₂Ｊ¦"Φ⟧⁻ＪT∨ⅉ⪪os✂5⊟)γ₂χ÷7→nＸ⮌Q↶₂xδ{iv0∧W↧êu↥⟦↥»β⁷⁻9PC⁼/¡OüσΦk↓‽“Ｆ13@J↨⊞'²º⊖ＧＸＸ⌈zd↧↓ºM↓≡⊕⭆¹κ⁸LÞ'.ＫＧbº≔→"ξH∕✳gm⦄2⌊Ｍ]¦≧»″»> ↔Π｜Ｍ×²sy±bW'▶?Ｒ8O|≡↙↔_v‴θ←ü↖´U∕.Ｂ¶⍘Π∨⊙↑Ｑê⊘Y‹◨∨⁻U"⁻Ｐ‹^γⅈêＪβＫD_ＴＣ…τＳf↷↨№¿№⟦∧Ｌsη2≧¹¡rν»'OE‽kξ>&ＦqK‖≦ÞωLü9⌈7\β‹[⟦Ｕ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NXv5VlPL9vWrIEgrAtJ3AkonSGuHgIBIowgCIiIgMBKEmDA8d@g5QOTKByKQYOhMQ3Y6YIza/9d@h7wAj3B/c1bON8ZpNNm7atVq5ppr1Urfq96JvrHekf/9L2r6f/PRla2ryLZhHrmKhKJmv7wYjZvoH8iOWg/wyUnUdB612I1P0aX17Ohf368iv6/Ot3SXYc3RTdGV7avzzZyryO6rqMn3WJ5HbTvRZWt0cTH6xdp7XZ7h0@v3opbvLZNRq7N94SqizV9FHGND2O9F41Uk0F55FdlPlsGbbQkyHHV8qp0RPq7xZeU@nsV2UctB1PJ31BTC5@aAcF9FLNFtj3RHzfi7b8CwVkQt@2PCH/2yFt12ZOua/PkMr0mfYU0Ql8KJNXGqx8IrA1O6HdsWcHnLwYOobQ1b1z6NWr5dRVxRmyM9urIB2fDft3K3w1gsrxOHdUP4K0WAICYHXuFf7QdR2@pVZAeHxz9dOcOvhbdGeq8iR9FNrzjkxy6XvChPyI@uUKiGN9Af1FRV@lQGhP8qcqpHomYNKvw8jcVwbos2YljjryJBPSIj9yCyuByNvyNDb3U7/hK1OEehDMh@FdnD29D2VcQtf94qVZ@eir2oOdJrLI5DuGEY7MPNF8@78FB0czG6rqnzOaPms0c4wU2oHGqkzngAyz/CqyRZgCktB9Ix04b3Hy3wTXN4Fi@8h@gfuueh3W4dTnIGUaPbTj690YnXZ7GB8Bum3PjSDLXR4TsYG2pIlT9l6CroEu5JbDCtRD6JWtZ1LWr@041/JTwtUiPdEvo4gAdufDAs4/CWq8iPFujQAom1qHUtH8uJcM@dFN3Frc14OkAXMDkGEsuhvHz8RRzB2QwbpDPgditR02YTRDMWa@UFnjaW5BncwOzH0304B3QYD3e6VkWZzjeb9Qg0kTfQdxXxTqbL85ctVxFPYvTkC46Jr8vH792Mo8c4lrJbpLfk2dXlOZVq8mInuTuSFz3a60@DkQZbGqieFft1xov57KbQiqJLy9Kjm6Yq8Ic33dGV75ATqr0NfxsRIXmGrf7gyIgz@Fdjx@OaCp7SX4ZQEUHhhiP14Qv9FFtlGEtw0Y5M/LGZC/3nc9S0PkgZI7/xPjUataxGTcEEnE96yqCEq8iv6LFlXLmNB/YSWnTdT1c42qOWtj3YwelDEP7AglT5/nwRfON2YQcWS3gGH34kIx2dUXMQIesXvgd3DFsK3JlOrvXLQHJykr4lzyewb610G2Y8lKPbRdgw1YgQ1PQ0cUKPGIt3YUjuYQ7fBDIoL9AMC@XY9M7B7obVsOB/SdFlm/HZWIYGlaLWGg1zsnCX6ZoI00QazJeMLWAmvDsOdVjXXo03QBH89hgvyADUgVNEzaGWaOCycwY6MJYzoq5DuLsdp76K@AZgUkii4KTdMAlEuz17Ak6JY0EnK9@lI/qf/8J78H@LswfGwEtc1u7Ek0M1eAigAd0NyoAeedbAqLcUtsqIdL@D7ObwALaia/uEF1vpEejYtCmcBcbyHA7AxVa2bvcSSPg3DSY2PnfiEEPxWcSY//xX@FNwshQZIaBtLr6XYQm3D75LNUwTMgiMQehjf7w4q6IUAjpmgZA5@NsrCDCeaCzD0ibHE3E0OJUL8a4pv9xWmOWDkhxL3NgcqoXrFeJNPVKKz@RFBtx4aVwcTsBxEJMynNVPf93aaO8Uh9AHVGD5Kn1cJCh2YNIqBhWgNpBValgqDRuDYttTCaczzA9ECM41xoO6XFBDEFiQKsJ0hGOLQor9ByXSD8v8A4u@hBe6nitog2HwZ3xWLT3FcH1mgA3gDc33S@xAnGkRyqxtz0eYISUsW5tnsRajAO6/svEEpm3O6urmxkgb246kbujgrM5Yqge8tsL9rsmAPIcS4yCRiuQQwk0hmx0wtSOcDQ1lTzJxWsNc@kx4hwC9@Hobq0GoJID0H2MJ6Wble6tuN6zIeNueSd30uqK4HIe7W9VWTBfbdgovhN92vsJxM5l3LIx1i58ooG89whG7JBLYH2pzNxNeCzg6EHuAs/1s2AbYCGPg8O@bm4UPYKBFbU4I3I4le6cZ/Svr0KIMdxI8zGdNjBlzuJeZLPa2ba0T6hDubIQC0jD827baVmZY4Zrx@VwbgGGO6PbUZBj5EYJvXu5iRSAIlGxx3m@E0/VTRTAqPWf7lWHLqAbAD49nAIloDC@TCXwQEiBDIk@tbFw3FhHEn7BKTlX7zOBDpjI/T2723yGmL9s6Wwnsx5aHeToCZQY4kd8vPdgMWzx40yBCPXAYngGGNwdeIyLmCmsVQfkB@AIHmaPL@ZV9Eer@uFux9JxGX1XEob2/V3r1LdhhC6n1ixVcwXUIBH5JD3UIdwNTheWd0N5AAY@xyiRYjjtftyc/H@beth0JRDmMK@gR/gnCEVErRK1oAD0sBEeqBP4gp0fcxYYJL8DBffcpz8r6WyKbbXX@1Yc3mQaoxwl9x4bQsefeMBB5pAd38MHbzNR6iF0LXSrRl5ZxpLsIfXhedWPNaCqi4W03vLNF@Jklb9CdYMSdRMLRyhZzdwibbU/r9kS43C0YFuggg3jlweNsHNq6Rg1oWYDXpfW8AuLQJUClVIHQGlmaKQjNzOBcNbP9WN4cMj5NEqChfcu3ZALF@daTVASa8t2NLBko0Leq5LnUbiO4a4A8NyG6voVwYGbZqUB0whmZeMgvLHRpZJ51fIWDwzlPgJHbjo8wgzx7Ta2Y/2TokXnhfvyG4ewWh@Aylv0mBugvqh6pyrRZDzAEC/AQ9iCy2ZeN1AGQtdgL4TmmkAxJjYAUIMrFsBquBgcBC6W13MZn@fMj3tFPYVIcK6MKPMhXLoL1eeKyHiF8bJFBwCxc2OQVl4oE2qEQi1NeJA/PMJwsG7BtN2FmZb2@rPup9D8dG71zC66gGAdC4Ue19D9ChAMkH8HFy@reIUyBKzL84hr8nlItWwtrEeCJIvwB3/VWQfYsCJIAJcJr8qunq@dx3Bcw9wV81eZQMRBMYToK4fhW51MsdP@uPK9GqEkvGanlu2G7C63ISCt5KVABeOY6TAdWQb@KtEut7BV2adLtdyFlJmImdY4E1Q8709N/6C6miDocs1zX@t9AFMDEtvNOlQxBcxHDjPPJ8DCpHkB4f@YJCZg5rGD3z01xCNDJ7oQ9jvbqWUaAr@4nVHx49H4mBRlmpHPWsHTBCeiwh4p0/6ad4OVQ3l3kI8tXbLfuN2ApfyVTnPsl/HsKSzUrt8I/Zx8@dJdAIYa5oIv6RjxbDm4JrTIV@JD0cKJoGLYSYUTrVoK8YAUBzfhL46dhiGZEqNlfg3B4qJuMT69YCUA1KeDsj7IYUqZNeAkst/64EJslzoxBMA@IuiOxswfaRLKU5wjRNXDznzg60JipxhxewBn670E3qaTS5kjhndf6FvS9AHPA86FzOK83AyYrnH@Kk5CN@iEvQiFRRUkwXRzdeiTctwDescKjWIbuNkOpmQDtDzK0MNekaMJuDz5LRw5YsRNd7Af34UbeLphnCQ/S02HJYN27O8rjtgfhPJbVFmxcVctYXlmXjjgRhJbhnXa@LyO1oAn3JtrwrggOx5Xg@Yoi6VkYIphue0bL8qCTDIUINNrO09uEDMdSHEPRmS@cKEysaw0yCOpEjnSKuuNXPDi/NtGBfDD9FIo3TPAekNgtAIQzkStnwQE1qA8ArgH4EYTHUJ3cTSuF4O1k1oFLQI5Adgnm6aZO0DOz37CAv/s@wE3ggIbpGdKm5VvPhPAYS@MycOMGwPaFAhgWnqyl7IXEtqV1GIMFHRwM2vUZi6Biin4rPD@cgEVSx58Z5iRaBVWdbbWezJ3/gDoH7z0haVxZS2Cyta2mP8Obhq05E4T@VHq604apTNsOOP46BIfUWAbopoqfsTdj4khcPo3H@xPvQIJWk5QbnyhD75OOIyx/GoukLjFaKBx1Kng38QoWg6rFYZVK8jB5QPqyn7yHkO/lBTynFiLdrcMSUFfX/dQ@OGkb89HXd4iURPhWkPkd4ICzuFzCmQFvrMdxQYqcIEO/6z4Wi8uZTCT3GlhniHIt23CIbHhaR7KMAINRNIPFAH5IFl0yPNBys6uMhbthKc58jB3gFX99Nz69TBNheXYX9MNOKrzNXaFkAPW61o9wXAN4hpoUWPwWoUo60eIiasxDUva/vuejomABG@qBw/jFkY5KYQ81BKzpIL3YYdniH9W3klCYgQ6QUp/ekqglnaOEg2VV9qyLvXsKQo@UDGnGMlgz1QNAtPjJSOBIIIPsJHwtZESg5mI2AKLqkXKEJBP1bxEuRq0YYkR9WTM@QyDdlAS1TGGpW7lIO0gU5vB90hfLVyZR@0GV3J29g9Wa4DBQcm8qc5rdSSblxOJM00vLaUx3gWJyTeva8HQlDiHC@KNwxuq8PV2rbh2XFx86bsC34W2Wf@rpAiB8UH2ILoUtV9buAYid4IxaOr/d2ngB95gsALptLqq@TaBUBq4P15Gh/xCHd19n6i7VCfmZ@UAx@t89MtCVAfhMuSUcbSis/5lhs8LejVgmCz/U7cWGxVjuSiUO4hgLrXeGWQ1RkP1hfmZbxZP45o1hus3zoL6lJvtGiE1b8K0DPN@g4FnR05/8T0SZ2w0e7XiAY8iLG0gHq3lzsE2L8LzDYfLwBh7KEA7ShX8MawGOAGd8NFwGu2Yw@ZqBw/vyJ7//Ks9uvGJ1tLJ2HR@mGp9hpApVmR3R5OZwGrQDtrH3GIkqg/61I4MdCQ@hzjIRHkXiO/nymqFCayF1Bg2WF8haoKa@xCkEYYoMLIzCU4m2gAZwSE@y9JL04HxNoAtip4TsAEY/6YG3wxEdS0@E78YtLM0wCFxeZx0TIqsJ6ShnAGkn/ORXDKJVNQEUWJ6pMCy61oOkafbVkW5DpJXvOFJkb3is814zwh2ppUMVKpsgi85@uFpiJU4r3L2qG3fEHlxkD1QEKtpeWJgR4XtKil/3iS5wRIjvr7ylKg3IGq@@9BnWClBasz9psBIakxcD0s2ii9nYfAux1dIB09pWycS8iWRAqI3ZfLteOX8b/xswbAiHxUX5c1rsyQvpvtn5Lk@45@/qWv4tSDt0exigUokUZYGzW74ZbEScwVWbIHoqck9hEb5vu1aSQAUv25AoQOTCCDvbDkpHQJg5Ak4qfYJJFPr9z3@v5Y4KD7ylEt9bVuEJK3bAqi9J/ixVTZS1rFGoGwnKtNmfInyFnYbpXmF@K9IRUqozDi45rrgolSCOSBSBjwC6oAsJJvyQwGh8ThS@5peqmgRvIg/w0DWgB9/dLEjYodDaQzuCqYOgWr7r2kxRnOoPeqW/2Ph0p4I5zT8rw6TfF/AZlWDWGxBmpnXDxIx0bOlUbdRNUBG7MxPs7hDh4ab3VMDieAsIuukd7ca6j3Wyzy7VB9xvg2eD6DlLaBE2fyywg4eI4gOVmVGFtYM@sbSs0t6hIu97PaziLN/zFqYUYGoT0LPT98owj6r8uMrk6nI14qlWXfvI4l95brj8gwg/72ZRBDBD5gRb2naUzCJo4IYBXWsYgrl6qX27sxtFkF@GZ1Uxs453knD@7hT2aS1f6ymK@c@UKuRcrDMt34cNSxMib3GxjBDuo2Y8QKozATKLT9/UyJ@T2STQFyxutzbq4JVPDNXSXLHPsZN3ef4Eu5VyOTMqvbUx4MHJR5X1Q28qZkrSZsvwKKp6y80X1LHwsB2XSHm3NsSlcBe9I9s/KswTvrgREGoADdAW0Ex8/reFsK49xCHbiW0mX3c5WwRHNSizzNr1oQ86@@Igtk7oRZEQSwdg7SZJjLtXmcLSXqyy/hHBg3XgP1VQmqNXeBewXUnpRB8JYoEkM0QQkB97XoOi1ABDpgbprba1fpwatB5oC7MgA0L/yeNZ77FTyg0c4HxzkEAF4wQux17AiLnCN5BVDx3qW8aiHklqNJZnFHZ/49ERI76G4deQBCEZvM1Db22gNmVtRRj8R9kqlEnowdGQOteHWQA6lm5CESzuQ3eoJsenFt3ee68JyqJVzxTFcVVmI3jv0oxHrSi2zJoeYQsCX6b1kOLvMvNbVp8wSBx9fUNsPUHx32C6H6A591uwNSDVkftecardBIBaDoPVrD1gVnG5ENHOxiGxl30zpthh0L9fFWX9wnk9k82GY2Q1Nv0tADCwQJPwN/BEtlX4Sy7EtzrxGFasZrUKCMBq14W7bkHVAg6Wy2Z/PMSaY9ySCG1dgxclA0d62qQD0RY5TURMdSvbkKHmkSma1jtbmG3ddBA2Ecex8EKj8gFNd@laDR2XgH0mtJvdkMUw6fa2RHx6o0z6esl@Ld9EOFmVztodsHV6y7dr1RBlpFiEbusmQuTuuEqvXxNg/TeG5U1aEY/BhsypKvfrOweYamKN0CC06s5E4eI1FlVV/o09FMSK1VkIPxkhGqAaCEDmSXKEoOua2hVcaf1hTGNYJCm1XDhyC2OtdcVZZmHBCaSPbY@M3NbtXZXscO3zMuMBXHe0vRAmPfnCdczq2uJ8U1WeIHyz@YwsCyJ0r1DRqBOoEVp1NBJNNxdnW6ohv5e5ZwckbtvZqO44AgO5wvGRsi2THHiv0VlN64/xUvw4u7mhoYwGgMxO3GhNO2iH6XwQb9sQkAfG8hjcehRA0Qj@ENZP4Qz52eLwI/yC9tvaSCzTT5mjXcz4l@eT8JrM0cfJOJFQx0Ct7QG61Bifs9gph4VPgFDM45YmxnD9FDO91RnrCCEdSwcl/c9/xaF@Cr6Icg5wszekqtldReZwfl/ymOqPAIot@zNFjDA29R0qGkBEL@rlGTkCDgrqzjz8@5V64pwgBDrg650VPtSqzhx8FldiWMm1Ie@Dj9cBJMhfIN1OXtp4dZNqvpmDD6V/rOXf5siKXWjSA1j0icvy6TS49GkeCYgZAFz8FgBn8Qtn7GAzbXeElvZvGxnmMzENKLDcyEBqNm1@xGFzgDw@pM7tm1PQdZZy/GNkunJ25WBbKyg7z71fw1YTuPBBF2pCbVC6Uaih/iBF9UkH1LG0PiPDN2uLJnHwEnGJh/qhkqJZ1Ei3G8ReeRNSI3mpOVgylMSLi1iDyVM1Gqu84S5TY2y5OH3pwn8rrpU3R/znq7r3cD6MNXronivbYi@NzdVVqKQyiZFPZihC0IyDmTh0UzXKNklAoRzio72GBvpUOsscvIUTac9AXMOqTmYsWjZuLDxRPdMAPjOfxSFQ/i1EvwEZTD4FlyBre3UIbQXd1rUayCTPycThQ8Fk6E0lHEfsvgIezf63NsNrDm@q0FDhmyNSA5qxQNuXXtZsSyzu17WnRW9ZO/1h@8vy94cUccQ7Tt2F6MwU7py4NogL7V@HJJJ9bFXYwbv6k4Rb@goVrfCzsbWy9Rrs7XLYsMJCLpdhQcHuBFMxrMJRlduaOq2gypfSdONFHYI2NIMjTcmzYdVaDtHKQYUCrA3yYZ8h7Aph703jXAxDl7GcadiakNcmp8vBdEO8tYK6de0aVpORycTrDxnbO3NYCSJY11pJQla@t2Eh6S2ATMrwvoVU7NwGXER@XNmenwbbMsz6FupMrdpYFk7WiaEhwCNbWUHdVMr7OZbgIQWce4ImKaFu2cgUwJuTctRT5Qz0i5EF/HEiHuaovYHjzLUXTDLOYGvznzgy1yDpr/zJDo6ZV9hgPP3siZs2JySc7sAwpcNOKAUXFxPgZb0Tg7odTmbpVg2K0j7iuflPB6qnw0LhNazJhhW07JDtGkhy/PI6dhVH2SnKpULCKS9qRipgbVjUrBUhtDLZoEFY@@voRGc40xB8FYnzFKdBUQenfJBF9nlO4gHhh5VZ7NJXiRO@TpHBETr5ynbzE3Jti2QLBN4yTChz80SByxas2PahDcrPKJNuJnZ/iSIrO9nxiarzva1c9xdsW5IR/wxWaYCWeZ@3Du9VT8KzUlS36AcL/INHrG39s/RVXy22eM3rpGUrolExkvtIF@oeFpoDfJj/yAjnE3TXc6KHKTjPSvC8ToQeZxFVV5BVDooH7hCtg9MkoZaNkWrotohCmf2JihtritepK1Cyu2/v8d4ASkTfWCYA6mGmOskaXGOgJJ09BWwu4cmths2wlnURG73lEPo6w9K0mQ/0/W18Niwp0l@GZcVO4x1VucK5/ffJfE3rULnQ@tkuMAcLWDn67sZKVZ0tfB6VXQonvcfu1LV5OFu3/BlPmkGmLninOpkJvx8iY/qp1t6Laft2R4aKZHxQmqCKjO3n2AiuFY9vBwwTXjkYJmx9sc6z8@Z5186G3yUST7ANJRD0zWSsvZ3VI/1VbLsdx6Y7eCOG1L8CYPUYthzj89uHs01yF1hs9vU0Mlf@ntJdt5hhdhoVqYGn7ucb1FeiYU25a1jvJmXBIH3Do3PppO@2nQJIMTijRhFCPDMAHP9dpq@fqTtXLHGgu9qFfwgmeMzy@qwSj4ggvk0nXvOkrhmVeEMyMDhFfnNbOO9/kIH62bQ3qg9yOkcX/lwgA6BAZGfBPHar//o@m8DcfAxSOMIuk1vFfhLWXADyBAqKmdEAWnagQDO8BkcFPgSgAmA7sqn/JRUMh4DCAD4BNsMvda3kGT7rUTcZZ7p2R3n3cb/qBllugWI76x4Cc0h3duUuLM7e0ER2sTiqglngBI1FjahkVthtCjUQyD3l0q8YADuAQUr6K61alUyreAiKVBdUqh3iLVQ1rOPaB4YIYs2mrl8ifJpXIP6mpy/lRdczw/K8q2xWOYYzW2UiJ@8ENWPx5YjwNwrtRWygAEhxfUQ1FoBUQIbjdy9VYggkYxPDCsZ@ilLMYq8AK@IIgTUJ2zTigxHDCuVIPOrKg@kAEtuJ1ZxUkOEiGRYQ1d83B65YYCy@BZNycZJDXEo3OSlCxGdYUNiLnR68ly/D/YombfOCMfhaNfLXbwPEd@CWk8IrPJmlPN2XtW6IYdvpYz61bMjzTjYowrTXIYpKMihokBdjiDJUaebnUEhFBr4yqWsyQk9JnaLOq7xUD7qkZ1px8HXko6QPqGquxZiYGba7PwDKMYi/w0lAwcxnc/JnE46b0Dunpi7OZ@ECEhWd2S98UHrmHfjJCLP514r0571YXY@0xu5gc2LtF0AawDb4bESGgeOmzXnFJP7UsnQ2@@6xoncOPa5X9Rqc6fcDfNFtfGZssin8nfC1bEViX8XiH3Of4AvUtectbPDoGqSFi88xk7nGIW51wiMQOtJhd2mHGjpxpLNtUxz/kTvYdlCwWbLlOZS2qJqJNmeqYZ1Li83bxOt2eZ4jz3oe4NtWpgqzj5xmTV3QbjtT557zYuj0YRW@Bxc@egMT1itE3hDhTsOmfP2AjU/YrWwYMrLUR8Y6yGNCtznLFAE8jkUowv97TaxvX1cHHbKl9wcewQBqIssBbDJYmejI8szhewiGDzyWbecNVMyGLVBgMGcAppwS3np2etcIb9uoVXkkLVUt@UvuFhvWOtXfWKP/aJD0A2jjW6ZXZLMjsScOs@@qIQSkPNWjcLEscag70gNI8BH6qEjBgfsQYk7VM0uGRdkOOISaJ@aYvGyr0v28rPV2EmilxrygZkygno8ZEHSipVzyvnvwHe81/TIgw1k09Lq/YwruBvoVSShSc2j@pDiOefByb0VdpJm1vpFqefEeSIPk@GNelVSh54Nx@tbsLPT85hrgZ9uT2laLUlEJdcBqcLqgEzKJvQ5oo63uiTIIm@o1qDHNvJHLMMAdv84uQOPdyuB/eGN1vpU@RDRFAbHuB9H4stYJDRvLuVBbfTc@LhPMKI/LSU4D6lYsyAbLD5blexlF@ddFaIZ33IZVXZV0qGuwYxkCrizbhDdBodfZC9bTHAKIxOr@hzmqjQDk/29rrKZ8/frZSxxgst741M/byAXVYUCceIo4kwgU/APm6hkYnLlHlnshvFA7IyuAwzArNiMzJ6nWeZ4KaE0Bzeo0NYtA5GSIvwNizPcPvGDzu2lKBAv0U3GZiDVqersg/FwC@NFauWp8/FE80vESZQvseBcsQmpVMC/YwO80RA8KUserIWOxSbe34GTIv3vPAa4n/UxSO2xEcAwOtdVBckOXujjXZKT/BsccVmFAFAC@vhFibOhBV85ddVgH4kr@pL3OGGmmc8M8Jo4M07Mqlv9@6KmONxlMV072DRzZ/9Zh5nDfPWMpB96rb82oRHLYXd5Sq9tzoXDDkgXNKAnOZodzgTLSXSh32X2yfB8oVLMR4ugRp0T2EOygG2f5gzhoIjTZpSrZhn5o4K1hfkvRItwfekeydI8wBg9VgbSKnP6F@MX7mh9MJixV9uNoXKcPhPOt8Tk9l9MSfnFYwDmZUHeBKtqYLuRuHPTX2HxnfgpZaq8LUOT0zRqfRKg5NV4VBD8gd2ozsswDuDzbJr5XN9MkXROWYPzv5j1nDYl0HrhMnFcjNBHlyfrW1HP6tuch/PK1bn/67AmPwCKLu0hP5pMxcZjG@2MsNMC60br2FhgDgATnBQPf9AJLT1BJBgCmK3ZUBgDhYFN1M07@cGwBQpXyQjrCuUW/2GtJb@lStegGq/0jNcbzhxDPwYXfHX2QLadGxb6zXe6yCxB6wyGeszIgwlpi1avS2I0tvKpFj0DEeQbP4qJ0iKP7nNONdOE8jZ04zrx0p0lfmeAk2zXl9ZFJXl1CY0FXMTMJuB@YtIn3aijxoW/OGW0QOJ33VeW1xhuPw34FJD/SZ8hyZdBY4iiVUMlxZW287HEKEuXK9wrVRbeDTaz7Vbvgn4QyXpbGLvV8sznC19mjglKbUURSuCFvKu0C1oxaHbDzxdoJf30IHVc9M5YesXZH8ellvkwDZvCi9njcWLylygRg9P7tl@MyAg2WyjAPsd4JY@xWgDBU1ZMAe0lGQIdXHuFocJ5fBsDMP2wsy7N5MBMbW8q84FWjpuAJh2WkB@AGF0CycfLewIBhzUFIldVOlhapvHYGXdVXtiA0roGHZYsdOLkacUuv6MM6HHjl5dxL6bkxXnVfhGCpMlZ0O4Z1DFIusiwfeVutZqkhcUYJ04i3BwoGZL@43yh/jpWpSvdAFZU@FZ8nqvR2Swd8p4NZA1zIobMswoF9M9Q3qkqYbGm9bAy7TWRjIxb2O2rS6gAaYcWxtSH8E8nlj1ELLNtSPyQhyCuEMyvWTkQIHFUnvG5Q3YBAggzGcR7yRrNqXwSNT3ps1IzjJtXNxRxpjnCaEGXN1/wk9p0OOHeBc6SyQBNHFQx41PGFee/ZtWWP/aBqmrTadC538xV931bjnTu3SBVIagOc6/BNxm7Ycci/vlfQBbeHACnX2DEOQnQ2ovZLEW48YFDdmGlE3tgNJTRUzkrH5Gjn3UQZmTrS@C7HrKWjkYVWSDWZWonb92C4FNWlC7M7HhuaREm8C3YNX7VoifCj22P9sWHNMmCPKcTbOi8Z/vlkeUbmgBpEtBuW@/BPlNIk/2f3iSLMoxEI1aHo2W/O6@GEOcPwu3SWaI/gzT1DahpxW90Ras9Ha4oblTW8HM@@GHmY2ouIjJ@CSQ0OQavC65B34Y0oh7QUBr/NOcgEZvmHOfagDI/0qespH9n738Zn/bRROKpJQQhrv@Y4o4EKLnS7twy@WK1GpHfZ@HkBL0H1pE2pC9w/iltsw6DHXXj5OawHEy5bi9n1QNlsOTAWURs7SUVr81KFG5GqSf9d@pnjk/EplZHn@JTQp6oZ9sPYXtQg1MmX2iSVYewvgc@OJeOT6jur2ULYb51dkG6a9eRLKU7Wb3zKe1bbP6Ao3G6cuhMPMGI3vcUP3uEIrPgFKBRCU8ELNNZHCOUp9zjHty98nOfRkvUtsBjLRp3wS38GYwt8Q93R4M9TWbG5RMW/j2RgNpmf//V95CbCO4n05ke3DBcjNEfG4hfUha6PqZH0/G@YE2W@tej9IAw/MwxXOtZPX39A7F5n7eVtBxnemsnGaRivSJycIAMdY3hz3jK1LKGiAv9/xTYtL@klp9@KU9iaNhZB4U8KABP3UHD8ERryybbjaSKiORffp32UkVjxri6Nz9Ws4N8IqAn1Qw7AxuEN5q@ca71D2Woa5RBhwKsZNw8FS3sH8X4KeISr6KUMPMAyk@qm3PdxaLKPrJlsKZUZ/GhP7PVPEf2d8ufHqsfX8dwErwczDVu6AqptERpRzc6TVl7bHhjLVdDII1jsGqf4SNRMUMVEWYdqAKPW/8xh/TPDWqBmAZg2U9Vwxy4CnPT43oNpJMAvK4rarE3pWlxsKOAng4m3CLpr@pkMpOXeh8@@kuGnBUQiy/6riuLXz41l8ARUvrDrU2TgFohWxCnn2xxUuEh8Uw5lg4leUnDfjTwk0ifKBRxkKIxanxpV@GUsc3SH@jqhi4JIKJCvaB38/83d02nE/ME15H9PdmdOzUtIPNKQcYvDY/4Z4aAyvsYGdKCVkrfVakaGVX1JH4mPY5qTxc4elkQmHy/hVtPzKYQpSIcH9cK3oL7OCiySyytS@61pMn6Ky4GAY1bJXNOlbBoCPuMR@v7l9WTOi52z/D6qQBI/zBm9xqYSKcdO6ihU3RebtxhPfiGDxciTRzcy4QWPahSdgjozqW1OYGxztFKe15Nkgi8sLiJ32tZm1C922JP@sjZKoDGdl8erUbrTfIUWyGPBXJVkz0ZF8Ml7bP87H5H7WjELv4I751MZzgWf871nLWhzdNPzAlMgiX7pLcCu4PRxQ@yIHcSGyLF6GZFATWuOl8qfOCkFcR3qmlST5@zGIe3qJpTJzooHzIaOT82xMXq4w97MPEKOdd8JTPdKxcpvBJ794M4cp5PZD@Dl6MgCay2UkIF4XhL43pQjusaFZ0S4nyRNyTN1Ry1CyYj0dI7RKPbD6dJJmCWbFMMhPCWw2bpfzeX/O6h6B5JWCm8TZ0H@DCYhEubhctjiRhJ1jeTPms@D94U3hT@vSsJpbghPjyJa3z5W90Hh69pzdlSWVBZhd4iMZ5d4QFJF6qebklLi0wxTAbsIyAc2gp7qv6mxxkD51N2BOf6mYhe@@Z432hnXFgYr2unh255E4MoNrmXypYjLuPq8NgneIYLd4C8uEh9s1SD54xg28HwMDiW4anFqrzJGaSHF9klOea2AFwEueO6v74b1uRrryOIwEviEr@gtchgHuXh5VUI8Y3L6la3mHrqHFC54Obx1PD6KLXPh7QXGogw/elH0QKVGkIPvfcyGiBkc0LaThZ2fKDoV0l3iEBHjjHuuSsc9uEMPR7w07KOfPoE8TeoHJfZ3itNUq6T1u2yMAwZQ7Fjs51XN8gyx/GVFOEth4bhaocVBPSxsPExlS1lP46CBNGzLeOMsK9Lpn9ZUFcubvPF3qgtd7TqQ7jl7L06fviUcJWpMqekjzp7NmRYV9ubQTdigbV7sDBmmVnYJNxdJMQ5Y2DEe2WhFubZiTwcN0TJYc5QQEVgQIABfjHfN0b9Pk9XtUkiEUEqxo82x4RHD9qhdalJ7LLWU9qbOdNJ/12GtKlZOe2M3Dv/53JpGfOFFYaha@G@2DMRm34ZuyEA75wWO6kSYGllryh1nrZ@scH@W8yRBRc/Aqx1tQ4WkucS2kQQRAgGVftrR9RhqL65A5BTmxrr@CJJX00Kbz1XvhsdEKEU1/trl2U09Ivbq1c2Ye7hBzbs4hX9B@vTTNLqZYyk2jtfFKcg9/hTM1qQaTX9AM6z8dRf7v/UdsZ@jkPyUVNJwx7wE4gzke9XPVXfnjk7mURTUjMFgO6zwlp0Q26q84AQGHOTbszrlVz8aOZ94WArx6/VTTkRPdvMqxhzr5DkKVBF8RyH0wQgkrKQScIoyRHtKi3A0zKtbE/jeXf7Az/gkEcK/@JM7O0emJ2FzNrzaSRbYrXMJB3Fo@1@4f8SAW7axzfBO9TdWtlMRkIuLYH4agv5vNfNz8qWVLa3FxWmJtD6VBX20IUZ113tyOQLWvgiT/wCjw0UtlXCCTLHTrEcgjmNYMaTYoKzjVk5FvfLArWThESF1aeBUv9ILID5n@4k6/K1CI1@yqbbhsUUE@SOpQIO@lZyh8pPzBV7liMrf8fLiHnP7pvflG/7qTt2WHHcJ3qmDcCKthMuQBFaB/BwrONbtwvNuRrhftCXDbuWIu8LmOfUbT3YaeqZIfNnS4hjVuvA9xtoZJIjqp0s/FTptKA9ww71Xvrcz1Oyq1jKHH8crnf7BZ93Q4bJVjQmwZDis6lEddVUuL5EzKQA9AFqpqwOqkBB89E5q2ZQ8KHYm5LkIJzdXQ3XD8qIsCcp7ez92RaRvGbYGPVIEjRU8448agp0qFZ7973//Bw) Nothing fancy, just Charcoal's default string compression.

Comment: I checked the Charcoal source code at its github page, and it turns out that Charcoal tries a number of different compression techniques and chooses the one that happens to give the shortest result.  The first byte of the compressed string encodes the compression method used.  Not knowing Charcoal, though, I need to ask you: which is the first byte of the compressed string? Here's the coding used:
RAW_ENCODING = 120,
DICTIONARY_ENCODING = 121,
CHARSET_ENCODING = 122,
RLE_ENCODING = 123,
BROTLI_ENCODING = 124,
LZMA_ENCODING = 125.

Comment: @MitchellSpector The `”` introduces the compressed string, so the first byte is `}` i.e. LZMA encoding.

Comment: Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 4):

## Python 3.8, 127 + 1 + 7315 = 7443 bytes

```
import zlib
z=''
m='AGCU'
for x in zlib.decompress(open('g','rb').read()):z+=m[x>>6&3]+m[x>>4&3]+m[x>>2&3]+m[x&3]
print(z[:-1])
```

Requires a binary file called `g` in the same directory:

```
$ hd g
00000000  78 da 2d d7 fb 5f d2 87  e2 f8 71 6e 25 89 08 5e  |x.-.._....qn%..^|
00000010  9a 2e 25 10 da 72 89 82  8a e2 49 10 c9 36 5d 46  |..%..r....I..6]F|
00000020  5a ed ac 36 75 9a ed 7c  f2 2c 0d ef 74 26 08 82  |Z..6u..|.,..t&..|
00000030  a6 f3 ba cf ce 65 ed d2  99 d9 f9 9c b3 ef b2 bc  |.....e..........|
00000040  e5 65 0b 04 2f 29 13 11  12 13 27 57 75 97 b6 34  |.e../)....'Wu..4|
00000050  10 10 58 5c de 9f ef f7  f1 f8 be fe 81 e7 cf 2f  |..X\.........../|
00000060  da 3e ef c2 8b 96 69 88  50 e8 3f 63 a9 4a 6f dc  |.>....i.P.?c.Jo.|
00000070  3e 80 b0 06 1b 56 8d 09  05 97 d9 98 8e 8f 5a c9  |>....V........Z.|
00000080  d6 e9 19 c5 5f 1c 2d f8  6c c4 3f 97 3c 97 2a c4  |...._.-.l.?.<.*.|
00000090  9f fe fe ab e9 d2 bf b6  6e 10 86 f8 ff fc bb e1  |........n.......|
000000a0  35 70 25 eb e4 55 e3 3d  be f0 24 04 ff 21 a2 d5  |5p%..U.=..$..!..|
000000b0  39 ee 6d f9 fd 93 fa 5f  8e 16 ec 85 fe ba 72 b6  |9.m...._......r.|
000000c0  61 29 a4 f4 3a 41 0c 5b  25 d5 89 ab 02 d4 e0 2b  |a)..:A.[%......+|
000000d0  be fb 08 f5 8d 7e 83 db  7c f4 a7 d4 1f e3 db b7  |.....~..|.......|
000000e0  de a3 2a 79 51 85 97 10  1f 5f 74 57 bf 57 a5 3d  |..*yQ...._tW.W.=|
000000f0  d9 a1 fd d0 75 b7 eb c9  c7 49 ad 05 0b 25 c5 93  |....u....I...%..|
00000100  bf 4f 1d a8 94 9d 1d 5d  ed e4 fe e3 cf e9 e0 2d  |.O.....].......-|
00000110  87 f8 9d 23 ec 8b 0f 9e  29 61 40 13 68 14 3e 48  |...#....)a@.h.>H|
00000120  88 ac 33 1d ab 4d 48 ad  65 1f 78 fd a2 fc db 91  |..3..MH.e.x.....|
00000130  bf 90 85 9e ba bb ac f2  bb 12 4c 0f 38 6e bb b4  |..........L.8n..|
00000140  5e 0b 9e 4c 25 19 3f 16  ae 48 e9 f8 a9 83 9c 24  |^..L%.?..H.....$|
00000150  dd 9f d5 5d 91 6a ba a4  fa 95 03 9e cc 90 91 ac  |...].j..........|
00000160  b5 9c 01 07 0a ba 0a 86  3a da dd 29 f9 46 01 50  |........:..).F.P|
00000170  f3 42 8c ba 13 0c 1b 31  f7 5e 50 c3 40 6c 16 5b  |.B.....1.^P.@l.[|
00000180  59 98 f5 e3 ce f6 53 de  3f 63 91 48 a1 c0 30 60  |Y.....S.?c.H..0`|
00000190  7e d8 15 50 bb 65 a8 45  6c 5d 7c f3 1d 86 09 dc  |~..P.e.El]|.....|
000001a0  e7 cc f2 ad c6 a3 7d 44  58 44 d9 b0 ab 98 74 4c  |......}DXD....tL|
000001b0  90 6a e2 42 ed c6 1b d4  b6 0c 74 d5 a9 c7 9d 0d  |.j.B......t.....|
000001c0  eb 59 b1 33 59 a3 12 d0  1d cb 97 07 b5 37 47 d6  |.Y.3Y........7G.|
000001d0  7d af 8f 73 9e db 79 bc  3b 70 cc ba ea c2 d3 5b  |}..s..y.;p.....[|
000001e0  43 5f c0 1f b9 02 93 22  78 7b e8 e2 7f 45 88 29  |C_....."x{...E.)|
000001f0  c2 49 47 d0 77 a0 10 b0  b9 3b c8 a5 cd b5 92 90  |.IG.w....;......|
00000200  b0 33 65 76 df 65 a9 87  dd 17 c0 76 e5 c7 ab 23  |.3ev.e.....v...#|
00000210  f6 68 b2 cb 66 1c dd 71  dc 50 09 80 6d a0 fc fd  |.h..f..q.P..m...|
00000220  32 70 fd 68 d0 9e ba 39  38 e8 c1 87 16 65 cf da  |2p.h...98....e..|
00000230  c6 4b ba 5b ae 23 66 e0  bb 9b 0f d5 f1 13 d0 9d  |.K.[.#f.........|
00000240  1f 4c 36 f4 bb e5 d3 41  43 29 a8 cd 68 f7 83 dc  |.L6....AC)..h...|
00000250  1e d6 08 cb dd ad d9 1b  9e 0e 9e d7 a7 f4 f7 c4  |................|
00000260  d4 99 1a b1 b9 3f 63 ca  89 04 e9 c5 71 7b 26 42  |.....?c.....q{&B|
00000270  f0 7f 9e 69 56 1d 21 01  d6 fc a2 59 be f8 e4 a7  |...iV.!....Y....|
00000280  4f a0 26 a8 7d 22 ae de  95 e9 fa f4 1c d4 18 57  |O.&.}".........W|
00000290  0f ce b4 9e c5 b8 73 3c  56 76 25 99 b1 27 e5 54  |......s<Vv%..'.T|
000002a0  24 2c d1 f6 56 ca 11 b2  ab 6a 6f 11 84 71 fd e6  |$,..V....jo..q..|
000002b0  c4 be bc 6a 34 c6 04 bd  8d ce 1c ed 9f 58 df 06  |...j4........X..|
000002c0  7f 03 ca b4 4f ee 1e 44  e3 5f b4 31 4d f0 d7 03  |....O..D._.1M...|
000002d0  8c 0e 88 36 4f 1e bb 0b  8f 23 d6 46 f1 f6 3f dd  |...6O....#.F..?.|
000002e0  db 93 df f6 a9 0e 14 28  9d 3f 06 83 f1 e8 80 f8  |.......(.?......|
000002f0  75 49 fb 0c 45 0b 87 27  4d e2 cd 2f 15 b5 c3 f7  |uI..E..'M../....|
00000300  d9 80 22 4a 47 ed 2c a6  89 db 84 51 2f 91 1c 24  |.."JG.,....Q/..$|
00000310  16 38 ef 74 00 09 89 ae  df e9 97 f3 10 9f c6 04  |.8.t............|
00000320  40 b3 7f 1e e7 ad 86 55  6c 81 48 6b b1 35 0f 68  |@......Ul.Hk.5.h|
00000330  e2 f6 f8 8b 0e 2f 0b 93  9d 32 9c a4 50 69 b2 47  |...../...2..Pi.G|
00000340  1f 7b 51 05 9b c9 35 26  e9 f0 fd e6 c7 2c 18 ba  |.{Q...5&.....,..|
00000350  88 ae 66 c2 f8 6f 74 23  44 94 9a c2 07 61 79 b1  |..f..ot#D....ay.|
00000360  11 10 69 be af be 63 67  cc 22 7c 80 7e 03 86 ce  |..i...cg."|.~...|
00000370  2b 0e 63 25 9a 05 e3 5a  21 ec 1f 98 70 51 b3 50  |+.c%...Z!...pQ.P|
00000380  91 01 41 f1 22 cc f7 51  21 29 08 f9 6d d7 06 d1  |..A."..Q!)..m...|
00000390  81 09 e2 cf 17 33 40 e2  07 a2 1a 82 0c d9 dc 53  |.....3@........S|
000003a0  07 8b 02 45 80 7a 5b 8b  b9 a9 87 90 de 01 48 4a  |...E.z[.......HJ|
000003b0  78 91 33 fc aa 6c aa 7c  50 54 b6 86 cd 7a a0 91  |x.3..l.|PT...z..|
000003c0  cf 29 90 a7 48 e0 27 5a  2c c7 fb 72 8e 48 32 88  |.)..H.'Z,..r.H2.|
000003d0  37 ba 4d 7f f9 00 ca c5  45 30 09 e6 49 6b 36 9b  |7.M.....E0..Ik6.|
000003e0  02 f5 a6 95 32 3d a4 d2  1e da c6 a8 ca 57 bf dc  |....2=.......W..|
000003f0  2f f7 58 b3 5d 55 49 a6  9b 02 a3 62 ce e8 23 43  |/.X.]UI....b..#C|
00000400  1f 52 04 12 ff 7e 60 05  09 ab 05 37 39 70 b0 9f  |.R...~`....79p..|
00000410  1f 67 0c 86 30 ad 65 de  69 75 74 a0 9b 07 3f 09  |.g..0.e.iut...?.|
00000420  81 69 60 50 01 9b a3 66  da e0 09 2b 68 22 f6 7e  |.i`P...f...+h".~|
00000430  0c 48 62 f3 aa 72 ac ab  c1 ee a7 79 63 1d 92 dd  |.Hb..r.....yc...|
00000440  65 3a a1 c3 23 cb 64 7d  97 9c f8 44 c3 73 87 14  |e:..#.d}...D.s..|
00000450  01 88 0a ed 62 ff 20 b8  a2 ae 23 1e 5a fe fe 7e  |....b. ...#.Z..~|
00000460  1f 3a a0 2c 06 67 27 f7  d9 fe e7 fa 05 6b 8a 2d  |.:.,.g'......k.-|
00000470  7e f6 6c 49 28 46 0c e2  80 ea a5 72 4f ec b6 fd  |~.lI(F.....rO...|
00000480  21 12 5d 92 e9 59 89 f7  ef a1 7e 40 a7 3a 09 97  |!.]..Y....~@.:..|
00000490  60 f0 9b 28 e4 bd 1d 43  e6 e0 a1 44 3f 22 e9 65  |`..(...C...D?".e|
000004a0  d9 e2 41 15 48 1e 52 a4  d5 28 eb 67 01 92 2d b6  |..A.H.R..(.g..-.|
000004b0  12 1e 3f 77 5d 6c 6e 13  1f d9 46 42 2c 5c 51 99  |..?w]ln...FB,\Q.|
000004c0  a4 5c 8f 4f 11 a3 56 d0  15 df d6 50 ce 3c 07 af  |.\.O..V....P.<..|
000004d0  47 c5 f8 4d 96 76 4d 85  ed e5 c5 14 bb 78 d2 b3  |G..M.vM......x..|
000004e0  0d 89 63 c2 01 3a a4 7b  d3 a9 7d 46 0e d3 f6 7b  |..c..:.{..}F...{|
000004f0  ce 05 cb 85 8f 16 b3 3c  53 21 b5 32 cc a2 8d 58  |.......<S!.2...X|
00000500  f9 2c b6 a7 6f 28 45 cd  dd 94 e6 a4 4f e1 3d 1e  |.,..o(E.....O.=.|
00000510  c7 49 4c f8 c8 14 c7 06  af c2 f5 04 3e fd a8 c9  |.IL.........>...|
00000520  75 8e 2a ca 51 e6 c4 f8  3e 44 a8 56 56 2a a8 0a  |u.*.Q...>D.VV*..|
00000530  90 2c ae 33 83 c0 ac 84  03 54 6f 3f 65 39 e1 7b  |.,.3.....To?e9.{|
00000540  d3 eb d2 c7 8a d8 b6 f8  e3 f3 fe 27 8f e4 c6 48  |...........'...H|
00000550  6b 5a 07 08 93 b9 d0 86  45 f2 11 db d6 94 4b 64  |kZ......E.....Kd|
00000560  a1 29 7d 3d be 87 8b 7f  8a 4b c4 32 bd c7 e3 ae  |.)}=.....K.2....|
00000570  c9 c3 d8 b4 e6 92 b7 b5  cc b1 69 a0 9e 94 3e 37  |..........i...>7|
00000580  ac 27 e7 54 d5 72 8b a8  b3 99 a2 6c 85 c9 dc d5  |.'.T.r.....l....|
00000590  eb cd 93 08 42 2c 27 ea  0c 32 52 1d ee 46 68 a0  |....B,'..2R..Fh.|
000005a0  f8 a0 9e 39 ae 94 3f 69  93 8a d5 22 6b 66 91 fb  |...9..?i..."kf..|
000005b0  f4 40 35 a7 10 1e 85 0b  da ae 86 9f dd 94 9a 28  |.@5............(|
000005c0  c6 c8 be b1 0d 25 62 aa  ab 9a 41 aa 9f cf c6 6b  |.....%b...A....k|
000005d0  51 b1 9c f7 88 b2 ce 69  0f 18 e2 53 5d 0e 2d 92  |Q......i...S].-.|
000005e0  92 70 87 27 b2 70 11 fd  b6 f3 fc 6d 41 66 8c 0d  |.p.'.p.....mAf..|
000005f0  27 ec 84 b4 2a 16 51 e7  8b 5c ae 18 e8 72 3f f6  |'...*.Q..\...r?.|
00000600  1c 8a 36 05 c6 79 54 9b  21 42 91 46 b2 00 11 76  |..6..yT.!B.F...v|
00000610  3e 3d d0 34 79 9a 31 e5  53 6a 82 cc 8c 0a 8a 37  |>=.4y.1.Sj.....7|
00000620  10 8b 28 26 67 de 9b 84  bd 61 c5 12 80 bb b9 32  |..(&g....a.....2|
00000630  2d 4b 5b 40 a7 c9 3a f0  c7 2c d6 cc b3 83 74 1b  |-K[@..:..,....t.|
00000640  39 8e ee bb cc c5 ad 11  c9 87 8e 92 63 83 ee 71  |9...........c..q|
00000650  92 78 96 95 52 d0 6d 07  dc 9c c1 67 29 98 1b e1  |.x..R.m....g)...|
00000660  9f b5 64 9d 0f 76 8e 31  d3 41 b7 9f ab 99 f3 f9  |..d..v.1.A......|
00000670  c1 c3 9d cd b0 af 24 98  99 5a c8 02 d3 15 9e 63  |......$..Z.....c|
00000680  27 41 6e 40 83 f8 20 5a  73 08 af ac ed cc 4c 01  |'An@.. Zs.....L.|
00000690  9b 1a 8a 1a b2 10 ad 99  fd 14 da 76 36 ad 58 1d  |...........v6.X.|
000006a0  28 19 de 2a 9e d3 71 13  8d 03 6f 29 12 07 ed e5  |(..*..q...o)....|
000006b0  87 00 31 0e cb ad 46 10  09 58 7c 91 37 90 e3 22  |..1...F..X|.7.."|
000006c0  d2 94 03 0c 29 49 55 2e  32 28 bc 43 01 b8 8c 59  |....)IU.2(.C...Y|
000006d0  da fe f4 d4 4f 14 89 82  ac 78 6b f6 5f 2a 19 c6  |....O....xk._*..|
000006e0  d9 82 2d ab dd 71 38 0e  e5 97 3d 90 a9 c8 3e be  |..-..q8...=...>.|
000006f0  4d 15 c0 bf 1a 61 99 19  36 ff 5b b7 cb f1 52 07  |M....a..6.[...R.|
00000700  bd 17 d7 3d 8a 6a ad fc  e4 4b 2a f5 43 22 b5 83  |...=.j...K*.C"..|
00000710  2e 1c d6 8f 7a 92 24 f3  fc 86 f9 e2 59 cf 2e 7e  |....z.$.....Y..~|
00000720  64 40 8a 26 ca 51 b1 fe  74 2f f2 bc 75 0c 28 98  |d@.&.Q..t/..u.(.|
00000730  5f cb 2e f6 5d 4e b6 b8  87 f8 1e 2a e9 fc ea 5a  |_...]N.....*...Z|
00000740  da 1a 1d d8 18 f1 b5 12  bc bb 33 96 02 a5 76 06  |..........3...v.|
00000750  15 ec c2 a5 7c 93 b7 31  52 8c d6 77 7b 9c 69 00  |....|..1R..w{.i.|
00000760  4d bf 02 b6 d7 53 f5 6f  f2 66 b6 84 2e 8a c1 06  |M....S.o.f......|
00000770  a9 9c 2d 69 3a 9c 55 8d  a0 5b b5 5c e6 87 00 75  |..-i:.U..[.\...u|
00000780  a4 3c 25 02 cc 76 42 e4  a2 15 ba 09 55 2b f7 d4  |.<%..vB.....U+..|
00000790  6b a3 7b 54 18 0a f6 fd  93 92 4d 39 1f 74 2a 28  |k.{T......M9.t*(|
000007a0  78 78 b9 75 d2 f6 07 c7  3c b7 95 89 6c ec ee f6  |xx.u....<...l...|
000007b0  4a 4f ef d7 0a 42 ed 99  39 9e 87 13 00 97 14 1a  |JO...B..9.......|
000007c0  f8 38 2a 08 2f 2b ee b9  4a a3 2e f2 1d 5a a8 80  |.8*./+..J....Z..|
000007d0  ca 0c 4e 2f 09 7e 79 c7  3b 7c 38 4a 69 0c 5c 1c  |..N/.~y.;|8Ji.\.|
000007e0  57 84 b5 f4 60 76 a8 da  d3 f5 f9 bc 56 19 d5 a1  |W...`v......V...|
000007f0  fb de fa 3d d0 8d f0 1e  8d 4d 01 25 80 3a b0 25  |...=.....M.%.:.%|
00000800  63 e8 0a c4 1a 8c fa e1  2e ce 68 1f 06 18 37 a2  |c.........h...7.|
00000810  fe b1 8f cf cb 08 ab 82  c8 58 2e b5 d1 4a df 4c  |.........X...J.L|
00000820  4b cf 99 c5 c6 bf 3f af  27 8f a4 6e 8e c0 03 d4  |K.....?.'..n....|
00000830  f0 e5 63 b7 e2 b4 ec 9a  65 7d fd 95 4e eb 0f 2d  |..c.....e}..N..-|
00000840  73 a0 c3 b8 1e b6 26 e5  80 35 cc 6d a4 ef c0 89  |s.....&..5.m....|
00000850  1f c3 83 be ac d7 81 d0  d3 36 e9 94 a3 6b 8d 38  |.........6...k.8|
00000860  84 e3 59 4d 95 42 70 62  c7 54 51 25 8a 4b de 73  |..YM.Bpb.TQ%.K.s|
00000870  44 72 69 01 72 89 69 c0  e7 d4 31 b6 bd e4 76 53  |Dri.r.i...1...vS|
00000880  d7 56 03 24 69 19 68 52  a7 3d 4a da 37 a2 29 e2  |.V.$i.hR.=J.7.).|
00000890  74 dc 22 44 6e 37 2b 4c  ce 69 48 aa c6 87 4f f1  |t."Dn7+L.iH...O.|
000008a0  96 5d 29 aa b2 13 29 02  f6 07 74 fa d8 61 72 13  |.])...)...t..ar.|
000008b0  ba 8e 6f ac 1f f5 dd 2b  3d 6d 2b 45 20 6b a5 4e  |..o....+=m+E k.N|
000008c0  86 b8 3f 1b c0 b4 6a e1  3b 36 7c 37 48 3c 5b 1d  |..?...j.;6|7H<[.|
000008d0  4f 5a 23 dc 70 f1 57 75  59 d5 28 2f 4c b7 53 59  |OZ#.p.WuY.(/L.SY|
000008e0  56 dd e9 52 26 89 aa 67  23 76 9c f6 4c fe ab f7  |V..R&..g#v..L...|
000008f0  f0 47 95 ba 2e d6 35 55  06 ea 19 bc 7f 80 d9 68  |.G....5U.......h|
00000900  0a d1 c2 49 0e 4f 76 fc  a3 8f 4a 5d 99 67 d0 15  |...I.Ov...J].g..|
00000910  1c 57 cd f0 7c 21 ab 50  8c d3 a8 62 d2 6d 2d 58  |.W..|!.P...b.m-X|
00000920  4f 9d 9e 35 0e b5 d9 66  a8 b6 d8 41 77 1c bd de  |O..5...f...Aw...|
00000930  97 b3 14 b9 3d 1f 55 54  a3 2f ff 25 9a 70 75 5d  |....=.UT./.%.pu]|
00000940  c1 50 46 ec c2 d8 7b 6a  f9 75 3d 6f 60 86 a4 c8  |.PF...{j.u=o`...|
00000950  10 1b 33 e2 15 e3 d6 76  ac a2 47 7c 8f 63 df b1  |..3....v..G|.c..|
00000960  db 5c a4 1c 20 5d 81 a4  7a 80 39 42 06 86 c5 35  |.\.. ]..z.9B...5|
00000970  b5 0d cc c7 79 ce c3 e9  e2 25 46 cd 0b 5c a4 5f  |....y....%F..\._|
00000980  55 2c 8d a6 f5 c3 de d4  37 58 b5 fc 81 79 92 03  |U,......7X...y..|
00000990  5d f1 45 7d 1c c0 0d 82  21 97 64 bc 2f 6b 0d 23  |].E}....!.d./k.#|
000009a0  0b 96 57 83 66 c2 48 51  52 f2 94 3c 1a c0 bc 81  |..W.f.HQR..<....|
000009b0  3c 2d 9c 93 9f 8c 62 f3  b6 be 15 14 4c 50 26 a3  |<-....b.....LP&.|
000009c0  13 22 76 a8 96 85 c0 58  c1 fd a5 b8 1b 26 67 88  |."v....X.....&g.|
000009d0  d6 9b 89 bc fc 5b 7a 61  c0 e3 e2 9a c2 a6 69 57  |.....[za......iW|
000009e0  a1 50 2e 7e c5 b2 ea 58  ae f2 8e f7 e6 18 d2 4b  |.P.~...X.......K|
000009f0  1f 32 09 ec c0 41 3b 93  91 90 51 d9 10 4c f6 ef  |.2...A;...Q..L..|
00000a00  c9 0b 0a a9 e6 89 0b aa  73 19 4a 01 5d 2f 8e 9a  |........s.J.]/..|
00000a10  e2 25 1d 0a 1e cc e9 8f  9e f2 fd de 23 6c 89 21  |.%..........#l.!|
00000a20  f9 31 bb 12 1b b2 31 76  87 63 13 d5 2b 5f ea f5  |.1....1v.c..+_..|
00000a30  13 ad 17 b6 9e cd 14 77  69 31 7b 00 7c d6 9e cb  |.......wi1{.|...|
00000a40  79 08 70 bb da 93 f3 6d  c2 95 c6 d4 d5 18 12 ba  |y.p....m........|
00000a50  90 64 3f 27 35 e5 5c 84  97 ee 8f 2a fc 5b 1b d1  |.d?'5.\....*.[..|
00000a60  86 45 02 51 5a fd 17 15  76 e8 d9 98 3a bf f9 47  |.E.QZ...v...:..G|
00000a70  6f 1f 42 4c 91 06 ba 0a  28 d1 22 65 e0 36 1e 76  |o.BL....(."e.6.v|
00000a80  87 47 20 9e 7b e8 b9 06  59 a1 ff c7 7b da a0 db  |.G .{...Y...{...|
00000a90  92 a1 6d 6b d0 42 f5 ca  97 77 e8 85 f5 de 5d 98  |..mk.B...w....].|
00000aa0  da db 0e b0 5c b3 a2 6b  11 5c 69 2f a6 35 13 2d  |....\..k.\i/.5.-|
00000ab0  6a 2a 6c eb d3 9a 12 70  40 ee 26 80 dd 7d 9a 9d  |j*l....p@.&..}..|
00000ac0  80 6c 70 59 00 17 05 7a  15 88 f3 8d 5c a0 39 95  |.lpY...z....\.9.|
00000ad0  3b d2 35 8a c9 08 21 5f  be ec 19 77 01 dc 81 87  |;.5...!_...w....|
00000ae0  eb f1 73 76 6f f2 7b 8b  eb 3a ec 05 d6 97 f6 1c  |..svo.{..:......|
00000af0  ed 8a 92 97 34 ef 1a 05  f6 cb 42 0d f6 9a cb 37  |....4.....B....7|
00000b00  f4 1c 45 b0 78 39 12 3d  5e c3 4a d1 85 67 d7 e1  |..E.x9.=^.J..g..|
00000b10  ed 59 0d cb 09 7c 32 56  95 32 c3 9e 35 97 f9 bb  |.Y...|2V.2..5...|
00000b20  9e 3c 5c 4c 1f 57 6c 13  27 8a e6 e5 f1 5b fc bd  |.<\L.Wl.'....[..|
00000b30  db 11 74 40 69 70 d4 ac  8f f8 dd d3 da a0 8e 0d  |..t@ip..........|
00000b40  fd 4c 39 9f ee df 2d 07  f4 12 9b ef aa d4 a4 10  |.L9...-.........|
00000b50  7e 41 9a 7d f0 50 cb a7  d8 76 fd f2 16 ec ec a2  |~A.}.P...v......|
00000b60  da dd 92 9b d0 d7 9b 15  39 bb ee 46 08 69 28 5e  |........9..F.i(^|
00000b70  d1 de 2a 44 b2 04 9e eb  a8 3e 2c a3 36 eb 03 4a  |..*D.....>,.6..J|
00000b80  d3 aa 2c 09 1b 40 89 70  23 3a ab 3b 1d 6a 28 10  |..,..@.p#:.;.j(.|
00000b90  71 6e db 70 cb 19 96 28  70 92 82 39 a0 06 69 dd  |qn.p...(p..9..i.|
00000ba0  c3 7e 93 d3 df d5 52 af  cf 91 35 49 6b d1 a9 2b  |.~....R...5Ik..+|
00000bb0  c2 83 42 71 d3 c8 a1 0d  ec fc 6f 2f d2 94 37 80  |..Bq......o/..7.|
00000bc0  f2 31 33 53 fc b8 65 5c  87 ac f5 30 5d 16 10 96  |.13S..e\...0]...|
00000bd0  19 20 cd aa 1b 4c cf 72  fc 87 75 a3 4b 58 c9 cb  |. ...L.r..u.KX..|
00000be0  0c 2b 38 b3 5f 79 0c 5a  03 79 69 76 27 bc e9 a0  |.+8._y.Z.yiv'...|
00000bf0  00 4b ac 57 36 8b d8 ee  11 36 1a 7b 1e 99 9a 00  |.K.W6....6.{....|
00000c00  27 2c c1 53 61 2c 9e e9  ae ba 33 e9 a1 3c e6 86  |',.Sa,....3..<..|
00000c10  60 50 6b 4c 6a 1e 81 77  ca 82 6e 69 0a 85 0c 52  |`PkLj..w..ni...R|
00000c20  6a da 65 43 fe 71 78 71  55 6a 58 34 d4 24 dc 55  |j.eC.qxqUjX4.$.U|
00000c30  d3 6a ce a1 da 67 76 bb  ae 8a 5d 70 f6 d4 bb a8  |.j...gv...]p....|
00000c40  31 23 54 9e 85 8c 9a bf  e7 24 7e 12 d6 60 18 fb  |1#T......$~..`..|
00000c50  94 d8 86 60 97 6a 72 52  b9 6c a2 10 27 78 ab b0  |...`.jrR.l..'x..|
00000c60  58 2f e9 e0 fe ca 88 c9  53 a7 94 e7 dd 85 d5 ae  |X/......S.......|
00000c70  c4 57 2f 2d 36 c7 9f 68  77 45 b8 e4 39 ed b2 f7  |.W/-6..hwE..9...|
00000c80  06 31 01 8c 24 af 35 dc  8a eb 0f 7a 5d 59 bd 37  |.1..$.5....z]Y.7|
00000c90  bf 3b d6 56 dd 80 ab a8  5c 8b 09 b8 5a 96 81 a8  |.;.V....\...Z...|
00000ca0  59 f2 1b a4 ba aa 54 1d  58 2c c8 4b 8f c2 fc 11  |Y.....T.X,.K....|
00000cb0  d7 bb 39 63 b0 b2 5c d5  f8 f8 6a 6d 8b 08 ce 6d  |..9c..\...jm...m|
00000cc0  cf 2f 4b 3e df 14 2c 2d  aa ff 83 a9 a1 7a 9d d7  |./K>..,-.....z..|
00000cd0  97 98 f6 34 78 30 1c a8  15 83 2b 6b aa a1 71 38  |...4x0....+k..q8|
00000ce0  89 0e 79 cc 50 6c 23 81  f0 87 f5 ff 19 2b 34 64  |..y.Pl#......+4d|
00000cf0  16 a7 8c 63 6b cd df bd  7f 2c d5 7d bd 22 15 f7  |...ck....,.}."..|
00000d00  0b 00 b9 e0 2c 9a 5a fb  a0 41 fe 9f 3f b5 5d 1c  |....,.Z..A..?.].|
00000d10  52 b0 7e 49 3a 28 5d 4e  c7 69 c0 73 5a df 60 c6  |R.~I:(]N.i.sZ.`.|
00000d20  20 64 c6 f4 97 c9 26 d0  39 26 45 64 75 78 14 2e  | d....&.9&Edux..|
00000d30  2c 2c a7 c3 33 38 2c a4  a0 71 de 19 9b f5 bc f1  |,,..38,..q......|
00000d40  86 a9 1c be ec b1 f2 d1  b3 9f e6 68 63 3b 97 8e  |...........hc;..|
00000d50  0a 1b 14 50 3c f2 52 dc  3f 95 d2 7d 3d 0e 75 21  |...P<.R.?..}=.u!|
00000d60  7d 99 20 43 27 b9 da e4  74 17 8b 62 77 93 c1 b9  |}. C'...t..bw...|
00000d70  85 1a df 2c e4 76 32 ed  b3 c5 cf 11 8f d4 b7 be  |...,.v2.........|
00000d80  ef 65 9b 40 31 f2 0c 43  6a d7 c7 a9 5a fa 9e fe  |.e.@1..Cj...Z...|
00000d90  41 4f 58 30 ec 39 b2 72  54 c9 f8 34 6f 0b 17 fb  |AOX0.9.rT..4o...|
00000da0  79 04 26 fb 19 6f d6 a3  ca a0 5b d7 17 ad 03 a7  |y.&..o....[.....|
00000db0  0e 4a 11 97 0e 13 78 f8  65 ab e0 aa dc 5a 97 67  |.J....x.e....Z.g|
00000dc0  02 29 49 1f 31 43 b8 10  cb f2 57 0c 99 ea ad 0d  |.)I.1C....W.....|
00000dd0  42 ec d7 28 ce b4 69 65  39 ec f2 4e 4f 3d c4 4b  |B..(..ie9..NO=.K|
00000de0  f5 7a 86 31 2f da e5 d8  bd d8 a1 c7 a0 64 97 a6  |.z.1/........d..|
00000df0  e8 05 a3 ca 8f 38 1f 3b  19 12 15 c1 93 cf b4 50  |.....8.;.......P|
00000e00  21 b6 c4 87 a1 bb c0 3e  14 89 93 aa 3b 35 a6 fc  |!......>....;5..|
00000e10  68 cc 53 98 4e 1b 22 bf  4a bc 25 dd 98 5b 13 0f  |h.S.N.".J.%..[..|
00000e20  8a 78 52 73 bc f9 58 21  63 1a 4c 1a c9 75 1a b6  |.xRs..X!c.L..u..|
00000e30  0f fa bd e1 e1 d8 71 b5  15 3e e9 71 6e b0 2a 75  |......q..>.qn.*u|
00000e40  e5 1b 7f 55 12 47 be 22  6f f7 8a 38 a7 37 70 c3  |...U.G."o..8.7p.|
00000e50  2a 3d 2f c0 74 3a 5a 9a  c7 fd 6b 51 85 0a 39 d8  |*=/.t:Z...kQ..9.|
00000e60  7b fd 17 61 e0 ac 60 63  14 b8 63 95 3d a9 2c 08  |{..a..`c..c.=.,.|
00000e70  f5 da f3 44 d9 ca 70 33  ab c3 7f 39 09 f4 25 b5  |...D..p3...9..%.|
00000e80  bb 7f 04 21 50 5b 02 52  7b 30 82 ac 90 6f db ab  |...!P[.R{0...o..|
00000e90  46 8d db 3b f3 c4 65 51  28 76 4b 80 a2 43 45 87  |F..;..eQ(vK..CE.|
00000ea0  ca 86 c2 cb c7 a3 e9 27  f6 43 b7 b5 c5 17 85 54  |.......'.C.....T|
00000eb0  19 82 9f a8 a9 02 dd 6d  b7 5f 78 42 7b 06 ad 9d  |.......m._xB{...|
00000ec0  2d 5b 9f 4e dd 45 a5 dc  27 35 3a 7f 86 24 1d 30  |-[.N.E..'5:..$.0|
00000ed0  55 49 36 5f f3 2f e6 45  21 31 ba 26 55 76 a6 b6  |UI6_./.E!1.&Uv..|
00000ee0  cb f0 27 f7 08 55 76 bb  2e 70 ab 25 ac 4c a8 53  |..'..Uv..p.%.L.S|
00000ef0  0e ce f3 ad 3d c6 fd c6  57 7a 4d c8 0e ef f6 03  |....=...WzM.....|
00000f00  2d 1c ba 7e 3a da 78 93  81 6b cb b5 67 37 8c a0  |-..~:.x..k..g7..|
00000f10  13 c3 78 f8 50 9f fa 31  f0 6a b2 b3 92 e0 11 b1  |..x.P..1.j......|
00000f20  92 9e 2f b3 c6 0d 26 f3  1c 29 35 bd a9 01 53 7e  |../...&..)5...S~|
00000f30  19 8c b0 5e 6f f4 da 05  38 93 d7 a8 2e 41 ee c5  |...^o...8....A..|
00000f40  87 2e 8b 07 c3 ef 53 18  ba 09 02 4e 87 85 1c d4  |......S....N....|
00000f50  e4 51 ab 27 c5 5f 9f e9  86 1d 7f f4 6e 01 5f cf  |.Q.'._......n._.|
00000f60  4a fe 12 d4 ac c5 db f3  4e 14 df b2 cc 2d b2 c4  |J.......N....-..|
00000f70  5f 8b 07 09 fd 69 67 95  0f 8c 7e 46 b5 2d a8 13  |_....ig...~F.-..|
00000f80  1d 45 60 61 e1 e7 08 dc  1c bd 87 ab 53 20 c9 1d  |.E`a........S ..|
00000f90  e6 c2 bd 13 0f f8 ca 97  94 f2 f6 cb 31 96 98 8a  |............1...|
00000fa0  bd 02 83 c7 89 6a cb dd  9a a2 16 49 3a bf 3c 95  |.....j.....I:.<.|
00000fb0  61 e7 c9 74 dc 4f ba b6  d2 08 6d b2 5d 4b 03 f7  |a..t.O....m.]K..|
00000fc0  78 0d bf 44 77 9b a7 b9  de 6c 48 40 d8 76 5f 57  |x..Dw....lH@.v_W|
00000fd0  46 d1 5c d0 36 59 df 9d  79 7f 0f a7 3c 05 c7 df  |F.\.6Y..y...<...|
00000fe0  f3 2e 82 e4 86 bd b9 d3  54 45 ae 75 8d 2e a4 e6  |........TE.u....|
00000ff0  9e 83 56 d4 da 18 73 d3  71 d5 ea 50 33 db 77 03  |..V...s.q..P3.w.|
00001000  fd aa 39 2a 3e 3c c7 8b  68 50 d6 e8 e2 bf 57 d7  |..9*><..hP....W.|
00001010  1b 97 43 50 04 69 57 3e  af 32 2e b4 9d 14 98 69  |..CP.iW>.2.....i|
00001020  6f b0 69 97 38 08 50 8c  ac 1a 1a 9e 8d 97 66 ee  |o.i.8.P.......f.|
00001030  5b 56 d6 ea 78 de 7f 15  0a 11 72 14 94 57 6b f7  |[V..x.....r..Wk.|
00001040  e9 72 36 93 a2 53 7b 02  4a 87 89 f5 6d 21 1d d4  |.r6..S{.J...m!..|
00001050  59 da a8 78 41 98 10 f4  3c 2c db 3f 87 74 42 97  |Y..xA...<,.?.tB.|
00001060  40 c5 85 6b 60 d5 70 42  cb a9 b8 c2 d1 a9 c3 0c  |@..k`.pB........|
00001070  1d fd 6a d4 43 e2 dd 9d  6f 3b 39 49 51 ba 89 f5  |..j.C...o;9IQ...|
00001080  0a c7 da 48 2d f3 b2 2c  d9 39 12 06 ad 9a a5 2d  |...H-..,.9.....-|
00001090  ac dd fa 56 9f cd d7 40  cd 18 94 90 76 22 da 08  |...V...@....v"..|
000010a0  54 eb 91 3d 57 4f 7e 12  79 7a de e8 a3 a0 cc ab  |T..=WO~.yz......|
000010b0  6d 28 8a 0f e3 12 95 e5  1d 2d 8f 1c e1 10 56 4f  |m(.......-....VO|
000010c0  8d 99 6d 63 b1 37 7b ca  89 07 db 86 02 d1 2a b3  |..mc.7{.......*.|
000010d0  9b 53 45 a2 40 16 df 6b  ee 7a f1 13 c2 f8 8e eb  |.SE.@..k.z......|
000010e0  de 03 14 0f 6f c0 48 8b  95 e4 29 f1 7e 02 18 97  |....o.H...).~...|
000010f0  76 0d 29 05 99 ec fb 38  4b af 52 4c 5b 63 28 f8  |v.)....8K.RL[c(.|
00001100  bb b8 c4 2b 85 21 a8 01  7c e5 5d f6 59 50 85 45  |...+.!..|.].YP.E|
00001110  b5 29 9e d9 44 eb aa ee  83 19 4f 88 bd 13 08 5e  |.)..D.....O....^|
00001120  46 5a cb 35 b4 92 68 4c  de 34 c7 3e 80 5f 4b 70  |FZ.5..hL.4.>._Kp|
00001130  21 65 cd 5e aa 8e 76 3b  12 fc a8 53 7a 19 b9 93  |!e.^..v;...Sz...|
00001140  18 2a a5 34 39 51 f2 c3  0e 54 5f 55 56 9d d0 db  |.*.49Q...T_UV...|
00001150  f4 00 5a d9 92 e0 85 b9  a2 23 82 e3 8b 09 fd 6d  |..Z......#.....m|
00001160  17 fb db ee 63 1c 1d 50  33 82 c9 a7 f2 08 71 17  |....c..P3.....q.|
00001170  17 a6 72 96 47 d0 b9 dd  db 9a 0b 5e 68 d6 52 c0  |..r.G......^h.R.|
00001180  4c f1 b1 69 aa bd fd 33  58 14 39 47 7f ab 2b af  |L..i...3X.9G..+.|
00001190  e0 47 e3 eb 45 5b e5 43  e8 8a bd 05 d4 82 f7 c6  |.G..E[.C........|
000011a0  23 60 bb c5 14 38 af ab  1e 8e 50 3a e4 fd 64 79  |#`...8....P:..dy|
000011b0  9e bf 99 5b 2f eb fb 7c  e5 0c 4a d6 be 15 2b d6  |...[/..|..J...+.|
000011c0  0b ce bd d8 43 ce 5f 21  87 e9 05 a6 80 9c 0e 59  |....C._!.......Y|
000011d0  f0 f3 e5 90 5f 18 0d ca  8b 5d ec c7 8e 6e 65 00  |...._....]...ne.|
000011e0  c3 00 7a 14 f7 46 e9 b8  51 a9 09 ad 6f d3 f9 3b  |..z..F..Q...o..;|
000011f0  d8 cd 1d ca 7b 7b dd 19  aa f3 0e 5b 03 f9 57 af  |....{{.....[..W.|
00001200  46 d3 08 4f 29 b6 45 04  ca f7 07 52 76 54 d7 0f  |F..O).E....RvT..|
00001210  77 55 ae 75 cd cd 1b 52  83 29 43 9c a1 f1 be 6c  |wU.u...R.)C....l|
00001220  b6 69 3f 67 79 65 44 bd  34 82 2a a2 c4 c3 ac 3f  |.i?gyeD.4.*....?|
00001230  b0 ab c0 8d f0 2e 9e 35  ea b2 2a 32 07 f5 75 a3  |.......5..*2..u.|
00001240  fb 13 7a e5 5d f0 c8 94  61 c1 5c 41 45 af 60 47  |..z.]...a.\AE.`G|
00001250  58 6d 57 f5 b5 02 36 39  88 89 ca 50 89 d7 f1 19  |XmW...69...P....|
00001260  cb d0 cd b0 22 65 3f 90  ef 44 fe 38 bb 34 36 f3  |...."e?..D.8.46.|
00001270  d4 e5 0a 73 74 84 e8 d2  03 ad 92 7b 3c 4d d1 25  |...st......{<M.%|
00001280  9f 52 26 eb ea e9 c3 df  00 4e 83 75 3e ab 17 82  |.R&......N.u>...|
00001290  8a 05 b6 6d 3b 31 4f 0d  87 b7 f2 e1 d1 9c e6 c5  |...m;1O.........|
000012a0  3c 6a ec e0 61 dd d1 1a  f8 57 25 de a2 7a a3 3e  |<j..a....W%..z.>|
000012b0  67 ab 9c 52 1d a6 7f ce  12 4f 53 34 13 15 ec 39  |g..R.....OS4...9|
000012c0  d7 05 1b 04 a5 21 91 ef  af e0 01 5c ee 06 76 16  |.....!.....\..v.|
000012d0  5a 27 9d e1 c9 a6 ce 91  34 e7 e0 17 98 0b d8 ed  |Z'......4.......|
000012e0  ad 19 f8 b8 0d 17 a0 29  72 e8 b3 4c ea 20 08 dc  |.......)r..L. ..|
000012f0  36 3e 53 d5 f3 58 fa f6  d4 4d 82 ec f6 42 48 2d  |6>S..X...M...BH-|
00001300  34 21 88 71 a1 8e a0 2b  4f 32 a4 bf 35 0c 3a a9  |4!.q...+O2..5.:.|
00001310  bb dd b6 b8 3d a2 e5 37  2a e3 09 87 60 81 88 cc  |....=..7*...`...|
00001320  bf ba 4a 3b 3a 1a 00 4d  61 b6 e6 bd 80 50 fb 2e  |..J;:..Ma....P..|
00001330  f4 83 4a 6d a3 5d ce ac  32 81 f9 b8 3b e3 11 5f  |..Jm.]..2...;.._|
00001340  c3 a3 0e 5b 57 ae f7 a0  ce ee ff 12 d4 d6 f8 ff  |...[W...........|
00001350  de ce a1 e5 3d c5 d9 1e  20 14 b6 8d e8 4c 6f 13  |....=... ....Lo.|
00001360  4a f6 f5 59 73 0a 54 e3  99 a5 95 af a8 dd 8e 57  |J..Ys.T........W|
00001370  16 51 e8 82 d4 c9 13 c9  5f 29 4f 02 87 13 37 76  |.Q......_)O...7v|
00001380  eb bc dd 8a bc 73 73 b2  af ac f9 9b 52 f5 2e 0c  |.....ss.....R...|
00001390  c8 18 39 17 dd 2a 43 30  3a 63 52 4b 62 1a d3 03  |..9..*C0:cRKb...|
000013a0  38 9c 1d bb c6 ae d0 e4  b9 d4 64 d9 f1 26 46 7a  |8.........d..&Fz|
000013b0  95 7f 8a 67 c6 10 1d 23  31 50 b7 57 b7 a7 87 ad  |...g...#1P.W....|
000013c0  76 cd c2 81 63 20 5b f0  7c d3 ad 92 ff e1 e8 52  |v...c [.|......R|
000013d0  07 2d 72 68 09 5a 47 cb  c4 2c 4f 82 ec 45 89 6b  |.-rh.ZG..,O..E.k|
000013e0  84 05 d9 c5 19 16 f2 67  d0 e2 44 bc 31 c8 0b ef  |.......g..D.1...|
000013f0  81 ef 8e 1f 5b 4c 3e c9  95 03 45 a3 9e d3 fb b0  |....[L>...E.....|
00001400  a5 2d f2 0a 00 d6 5a 7c  f5 95 ea 0a c9 8f ee 33  |.-....Z|.......3|
00001410  d6 65 df 73 cd a5 0c 84  63 4f 63 10 ea 3b 6f cc  |.e.s....cOc..;o.|
00001420  40 df 7a 4e db d5 50 8f  dc 85 0d 42 b9 02 34 32  |@.zN..P....B..42|
00001430  41 f6 3a df 4f 22 b8 2e  d8 71 82 a8 28 c9 eb 2f  |A.:.O"...q..(../|
00001440  ea 46 c0 e4 66 82 25 5f  77 c6 3b 35 f1 04 ff 7b  |.F..f.%_w.;5...{|
00001450  57 5d cc 80 89 48 cd ba  d2 9d ce ec f1 d2 59 33  |W]...H........Y3|
00001460  4b 7b 82 be f7 71 89 29  f6 eb 6b 6b 28 02 63 25  |K{...q.)..kk(.c%|
00001470  5f 1e 2c da 70 4d 8e 58  54 cb 94 4a c6 37 56 da  |_.,.pM.XT..J.7V.|
00001480  c1 6a 1d d7 e8 05 ef 33  a7 51 94 8c 25 8b b8 32  |.j.....3.Q..%..2|
00001490  22 d4 8e 0a 01 09 43 5c  aa ed 5a 93 c4 2a 94 7d  |".....C\..Z..*.}|
000014a0  2c e2 f3 3d 26 fb 3a b1  61 68 c3 60 b5 e0 6e 23  |,..=&.:.ah.`..n#|
000014b0  44 0b 77 2f e3 67 2c 9b  47 8b bc b6 7b 38 ac fb  |D.w/.g,.G...{8..|
000014c0  cc 04 5f ee 4e 08 97 78  16 fc 40 af 89 54 7c a7  |.._.N..x..@..T|.|
000014d0  5c 6e dc 39 27 2a 1c 7c  dd 47 be fb e1 02 03 99  |\n.9'*.|.G......|
000014e0  62 52 39 5f c4 a3 1b e0  33 b0 82 f3 40 e1 b0 37  |bR9_....3...@..7|
000014f0  ef e3 53 ad 77 49 74 eb  74 f9 a0 89 6b 3d 6c 40  |..S.wIt.t...k=l@|
00001500  99 81 4a cd 1d e0 02 9f  d6 07 c2 09 b0 e7 f3 31  |..J............1|
00001510  d8 66 7e c6 fc fb 64 27  c9 91 dc 30 71 d5 6f 3f  |.f~...d'...0q.o?|
00001520  27 d9 07 6a a9 f4 83 d2  1f 65 b9 f8 b0 64 4d 31  |'..j.....e...dM1|
00001530  43 96 9c 31 d5 f6 b9 0a  35 7f e5 cc 6f 1b c5 fe  |C..1....5...o...|
00001540  82 dd 40 7a 15 a3 2c b1  66 3a 6d 88 2f 90 92 d8  |..@z..,.f:m./...|
00001550  f2 59 2c 23 f7 5e ad c7  d2 b2 17 33 aa bb 24 b6  |.Y,#.^.....3..$.|
00001560  d7 71 2d c2 a1 5c bf 0a  b4 48 81 e6 df 91 b3 c6  |.q-..\...H......|
00001570  43 0d 1d cb f7 9f a3 71  98 ef 1d c1 93 f1 b3 a0  |C......q........|
00001580  fc 6d 33 69 50 1a f2 34  36 26 58 c5 cd 7b 16 64  |.m3iP..46&X..{.d|
00001590  83 b8 3e 00 8a 02 80 03  7d cd be 6e 93 52 72 22  |..>.....}..n.Rr"|
000015a0  3c 24 38 32 de 54 41 f3  7c b8 38 f3 6b 37 e3 a9  |<$82.TA.|.8.k7..|
000015b0  74 ca 94 82 79 3e 2c b3  52 9e eb 6c 33 0d a9 61  |t...y>,.R..l3..a|
000015c0  5b 2e 54 48 ad fa 7a 4e  f0 b5 96 92 f8 cc bc 0a  |[.TH..zN........|
000015d0  da cc 22 2a 96 c5 90 17  5c 59 64 e7 7b e0 e9 9a  |.."*....\Yd.{...|
000015e0  ed 08 6d 21 6d 66 41 3f  eb da 65 6e a7 0b 06 1c  |..m!mfA?..en....|
000015f0  27 4f fb 11 99 db 1b 7f  ae 6a 1b a8 d4 f2 f6 01  |'O.......j......|
00001600  28 ae 74 40 9e a6 e4 f7  7e 3d a8 e5 71 7b ef c4  |(.t@....~=..q{..|
00001610  44 57 29 3c 3e c4 76 57  7b 64 bc 6f a5 1f d4 40  |DW)<>.vW{d.o...@|
00001620  64 14 83 70 d4 eb 0c a1  3b c5 1b 53 1a d1 68 7b  |d..p....;..S..h{|
00001630  bc 8d 03 fb d7 fd 42 d4  6a 08 41 97 33 ac a9 f8  |......B.j.A.3...|
00001640  55 d3 17 4a 3a e9 59 a6  b5 53 2d 7b da eb 9c 45  |U..J:.Y..S-{...E|
00001650  7c 0b 3c 68 72 ba c5 69  92 a6 9d e7 c6 b7 31 7f  ||.<hr..i......1.|
00001660  33 95 bb d7 ce 20 14 fd  92 2b fc 0c 79 f1 a0 c9  |3.... ...+..y...|
00001670  0f 39 7a a9 c2 9b f8 b6  ba cb 2c dc a2 70 72 16  |.9z.......,..pr.|
00001680  7a 8a 5a 16 7f 18 b2 37  4f e4 a2 be fb e9 ef 1f  |z.Z....7O.......|
00001690  cd 57 0d 99 9f 6e ad cb  47 ae 4b ea d1 a8 56 9d  |.W...n..G.K...V.|
000016a0  62 70 7a db d9 f9 b5 00  20 ee 9a 62 9b 51 c3 ad  |bpz..... ..b.Q..|
000016b0  0d 94 de 9c 8d 59 17 4e  df 63 a8 75 c7 23 6f 04  |.....Y.N.c.u.#o.|
000016c0  03 3c 51 4a 2b 50 8d b3  be a6 b3 8e 06 55 38 70  |.<QJ+P.......U8p|
000016d0  39 a0 f6 a6 00 a0 34 40  20 f0 0a f0 ed 28 30 43  |9.....4@ ....(0C|
000016e0  5b 6c 05 36 a1 b4 db c7  d3 20 4d 4d 11 3d 2a 66  |[l.6..... MM.=*f|
000016f0  3a c9 8d c3 e0 9d 61 15  ec 6e 48 90 36 ef aa f6  |:.....a..nH.6...|
00001700  b4 53 17 12 d7 63 68 03  7b 5f 19 88 07 ca 06 74  |.S...ch.{_.....t|
00001710  6d 2c 68 de b5 a0 8e 9d  0e ee 9f aa 83 49 a3 7b  |m,h..........I.{|
00001720  71 7b 6b 45 63 34 c1 02  a3 7c 0d c9 4e e4 23 6b  |q{kEc4...|..N.#k|
00001730  56 b8 6d 59 8d db 8f 03  41 74 7a 6f af 37 51 47  |V.mY....Atzo.7QG|
00001740  2f 41 35 25 90 2c 7d 91  98 8e 15 88 3b ac ce dc  |/A5%.,}.....;...|
00001750  8b 6c 8b b2 e2 d9 5c 38  29 aa 17 28 12 b9 31 00  |.l....\8)..(..1.|
00001760  f4 f4 33 f7 3f 1d 02 de  4b ea 7a a8 26 42 d3 76  |..3.?...K.z.&B.v|
00001770  31 d7 8c 5d cb 51 2e 9b  45 33 b3 15 cd c1 21 93  |1..].Q..E3....!.|
00001780  ba 60 a7 8e 08 bd 9e cd  21 9d 0b 06 85 38 00 43  |.`......!....8.C|
00001790  e6 db 4b e9 ca 67 bf 6d  6c b4 6f 15 cd 4f 3a a9  |..K..g.ml.o..O:.|
000017a0  b9 ca df d6 9a 40 27 dc  42 dd bd 3b ae ae 14 50  |.....@'.B..;...P|
000017b0  29 e9 d9 ad 7d 46 9f 1f  7a b1 6d d4 37 8d 0b 67  |)...}F..z.m.7..g|
000017c0  d8 4f b4 05 d3 86 43 e1  3d 86 9d ca 71 96 2b 28  |.O....C.=...q.+(|
000017d0  df 25 84 b7 da cf 48 4b  ee a1 42 b7 cc 67 b3 67  |.%....HK..B..g.g|
000017e0  65 2a 6b 56 67 77 2c cb  e1 2d 22 3c bc 68 d5 6d  |e*kVgw,..-"<.h.m|
000017f0  b8 20 19 20 34 fd b5 fb  c8 88 75 18 03 9a f5 b0  |. . 4.....u.....|
00001800  fb cc 53 b4 24 b3 e6 8d  e8 45 e8 bb 29 72 5f 79  |..S.$....E..)r_y|
00001810  b1 3d aa 40 b3 9e 38 53  84 b3 b3 75 35 a7 b0 15  |.=.@..8S...u5...|
00001820  f3 46 f3 db a6 46 d7 f9  7b 63 50 87 fa cd 84 c7  |.F...F..{cP.....|
00001830  b7 75 82 b3 66 5a 0f 9e  7c 84 94 c2 e0 53 b2 26  |.u..fZ..|....S.&|
00001840  71 7b 88 4a 29 b3 a9 36  78 5f aa 62 a0 19 68 fc  |q{.J)..6x_.b..h.|
00001850  2f 45 c9 5f 5f 4b da 3f  f1 9d f4 6f ab 76 d3 3b  |/E.__K.?...o.v.;|
00001860  4e 92 64 1c 68 fe af 17  a0 ad c0 09 d0 c9 55 44  |N.d.h.........UD|
00001870  e4 c3 de 0b 8d 24 d3 1a  a9 c2 65 d2 c7 78 27 da  |.....$....e..x'.|
00001880  81 6b bc b1 55 c9 fe bb  fe 6d 8b 52 7a 58 61 b9  |.k..U....m.RzXa.|
00001890  14 2d 93 56 66 05 51 0a  f6 a4 15 99 eb 8d 82 c0  |.-.Vf.Q.........|
000018a0  1e 92 32 55 a8 f2 38 57  93 66 4c 47 46 f4 0b b6  |..2U..8W.fLGF...|
000018b0  20 0e c2 22 32 d2 26 23  58 a5 f0 c3 23 9e 13 94  | .."2.&#X...#...|
000018c0  e1 e6 3d ed e2 03 d0 93  e0 95 4a d8 38 4f 85 c7  |..=.......J.8O..|
000018d0  92 3a 36 88 b6 1b fa 89  04 54 76 0c 5e cb 83 9b  |.:6......Tv.^...|
000018e0  e2 2c dd 72 32 8a 47 b9  ca 84 1b 05 ee b6 3f bc  |.,.r2.G.......?.|
000018f0  e2 fe 35 db 14 dc 8a 3c  21 b2 b3 02 df 3c 32 3c  |..5....<!....<2<|
00001900  57 2f ad 2c dd af c9 3e  42 a2 26 64 f0 ff 16 12  |W/.,...>B.&d....|
00001910  53 cd 4d b4 ce 55 7b 00  89 f4 56 8d a5 9c db 71  |S.M..U{...V....q|
00001920  e8 b8 ed 87 c9 3c ce 95  f8 b1 20 d7 74 6d 83 1e  |.....<.... .tm..|
00001930  32 09 7c ef 7d 78 cb 0a  7d 90 e1 09 79 a1 99 d4  |2.|.}x..}...y...|
00001940  0e 1e 21 06 d9 69 7c 0f  3f 5f 8a da bd 73 31 af  |..!..i|.?_...s1.|
00001950  f7 53 a2 ed 2b 66 94 6c  ff 33 b5 28 bf bf f2 91  |.S..+f.l.3.(....|
00001960  7f e4 99 7c c5 67 19 46  ad 2b 7b 5b 82 8a 7d 8b  |...|.g.F.+{[..}.|
00001970  33 53 56 e0 fe aa 29 e5  f6 b4 97 cd 37 48 c6 4c  |3SV...).....7H.L|
00001980  f2 2c e8 ca e6 a7 f9 ce  a5 92 55 97 e4 91 84 5a  |.,........U....Z|
00001990  70 43 b1 a5 b3 6c c4 fb  3e fb fe ab 3b 75 5b e6  |pC...l..>...;u[.|
000019a0  a7 99 83 3d 93 e6 5b 7d  4f 57 89 9e 53 a1 5f 6c  |...=..[}OW..S._l|
000019b0  67 d6 26 54 fe 14 55 fb  ec 97 73 e9 bf d0 47 f1  |g.&T..U...s...G.|
000019c0  dd 8f 5e 35 10 9a 4e ad  cb 32 37 4d e5 dd 47 5e  |..^5..N..27M..G^|
000019d0  f5 db e5 a8 b7 d8 37 af  54 b5 2c 6f f0 75 97 63  |......7.T.,o.u.c|
000019e0  7e 96 9f 5f 45 90 69 f0  e6 3b 4f ab 5a 73 92 75  |~.._E.i..;O.Zs.u|
000019f0  4e 57 cc d4 32 9c e5 4f  ff 2a d7 5d 4c 9c 0b 49  |NW..2..O.*.]L..I|
00001a00  56 a0 68 8f 73 bd 01 2f  18 f9 96 3c 42 67 e0 16  |V.h.s../...<Bg..|
00001a10  0a c4 48 0f e8 40 9c 24  27 3f 47 85 31 23 63 53  |..H..@.$'?G.1#cS|
00001a20  c2 34 b2 8f bb 40 76 8b  67 35 9e dc f1 05 a9 96  |.4...@v.g5......|
00001a30  bd 44 ec cd e6 cc 16 0a  a3 a5 32 f4 c0 35 4f 7e  |.D........2..5O~|
00001a40  e7 7f 5f cc 88 f5 1f df  ae 20 0b 7c 1d b9 ba dd  |.._...... .|....|
00001a50  0e 91 13 60 7f b8 fc 8e  0c df 90 c6 bd 75 3b 8d  |...`.........u;.|
00001a60  df 2e 1b df 6a 6e 0a c7  36 21 6c cf 45 80 d8 f5  |....jn..6!l.E...|
00001a70  43 c9 3c 9f dc e1 74 77  08 d0 a1 68 8d 5a da 83  |C.<...tw...h.Z..|
00001a80  ca dd f6 e9 80 43 7e 5d  86 04 40 a5 da 97 80 e2  |.....C~]..@.....|
00001a90  09 09 a2 e4 0c 59 4d ba  fe f9 ff c5 a1 1e 93 e7  |.....YM.........|
00001aa0  51 70 9a 50 5f d1 b3 d9  84 9c b7 1d a6 26 c0 cd  |Qp.P_........&..|
00001ab0  77 a8 58 d6 31 4e bf 7b  52 35 98 b2 b8 1b 7d 76  |w.X.1N.{R5....}v|
00001ac0  08 b4 d1 ee a5 a3 ea eb  28 05 c5 83 69 5f bb ab  |........(...i_..|
00001ad0  ff 90 fc 29 2a 09 fb 8c  1f e7 15 cd ac 87 c7 41  |...)*..........A|
00001ae0  9f cc 4b e6 af 98 be 1a  61 92 bc d9 69 cb 8d 1c  |..K.....a...i...|
00001af0  d3 2e a3 5b f6 b1 60 10  b9 43 5e f9 06 b4 f1 71  |...[..`..C^....q|
00001b00  ea b1 9b 36 7e d1 a9 89  3c e1 6a 74 6c d6 d9 03  |...6~...<.jtl...|
00001b10  ad 7f fc 2c 0d 72 e0 a7  6f f6 79 bf 26 2b ae 48  |...,.r..o.y.&+.H|
00001b20  1a 5f 7b d8 21 4c 69 62  c6 c9 5e 7c 1b de 74 e5  |._{.!Lib..^|..t.|
00001b30  29 0d 2f 8a fc 30 ec 14  74 55 f1 1a ac fc f6 91  |)./..0..tU......|
00001b40  8c 3a ed 9b 95 48 70 7a  6b 2f ab c6 43 ec cf 1f  |.:...Hpzk/..C...|
00001b50  2d 63 8e 92 ee a6 e8 e0  b0 7f a4 29 8b 4b 1e bc  |-c.........).K..|
00001b60  75 55 2d ef 85 6d d2 4b  ff 1d 3c 36 8d 1c 0b ae  |uU-..m.K..<6....|
00001b70  97 93 ee ef 83 13 d6 41  05 db 37 99 67 9b df b9  |.......A..7.g...|
00001b80  64 be 3a f9 cb b3 ee a3  87 4b 5a cd 99 ee 84 96  |d.:......KZ.....|
00001b90  1b d1 7f 44 3c 1f 9b 4d  19 15 bd 53 ab bb e6 f4  |...D<..M...S....|
00001ba0  8d e9 96 c3 d4 b7 25 21  02 ea a8 ec 5d 38 ae a9  |......%!....]8..|
00001bb0  0c 71 7d 30 73 67 ec 31  7b 90 79 ff 22 e8 cb b1  |.q}0sg.1{.y."...|
00001bc0  0e 70 a7 a8 b2 2d ea f7  4b 47 df 6b c6 1d db 07  |.p...-..KG.k....|
00001bd0  f5 bd 75 fb c4 4c 73 d3  09 8d 1c be f7 6f e8 9a  |..u..Ls......o..|
00001be0  c8 f9 cd cb 93 2f 7b 7e  42 fe 7c 79 35 25 a0 6d  |...../{~B.|y5%.m|
00001bf0  e0 ef 07 b4 cb c3 31 f5  dd d0 95 65 f0 71 a8 1b  |......1....e.q..|
00001c00  66 be 0e 54 04 45 aa de  ec 14 10 7e 8b 8d 39 24  |f..T.E.....~..9$|
00001c10  db 87 03 c3 5e d2 64 4e  1c b2 dd 3c d9 8c 8e 11  |....^.dN...<....|
00001c20  8c e7 4e be d0 5d 62 9c  cf 7b 2e 10 ad e1 9e 3e  |..N..]b..{.....>|
00001c30  6e ad 48 40 b4 f4 23 ba  9a fb 70 17 59 05 c9 10  |n.H@..#...p.Y...|
00001c40  fe cf c0 7f 6c a7 17 1b  12 5c 97 90 a8 6f a7 e5  |....l....\...o..|
00001c50  73 b8 2a 2a 16 61 7d 4e  88 4c b7 6e 18 a6 69 6f  |s.**.a}N.L.n..io|
00001c60  9d 73 c0 ca fa 18 9b ff  5d f6 59 f6 91 1f 39 31  |.s......].Y...91|
00001c70  6a 51 f9 5b 6f ac 2f ae  84 dc 45 ea a1 33 de 2a  |jQ.[o./...E..3.*|
00001c80  dd f1 3b b5 40 10 5b 7c  16 89 03 fd ff fe 17 14  |..;.@.[|........|
00001c90  31 cb d1                                          |1..|
00001c93
```

To generate this file using Python 3.8: (not part of the solution, just informational)

```
from pathlib import Path
import math
import zlib

DIRECTORY = Path(__file__).parent
genome = (DIRECTORY / 'covid_genome.txt').read_text()
mapping = {t: i for i, t in enumerate('AGCU')}
buff = bytearray(math.ceil(len(genome) / 4))
buff_i = 0
buff_shift = 6
for c in genome:
    buff[buff_i] |= mapping[c] << buff_shift
    if buff_shift > 0:
        buff_shift -= 2
    else:
        buff_i += 1
        buff_shift = 6
(DIRECTORY / 'g').write_bytes(zlib.compress(buff, 9))
```

(I know I can probably shave off one byte by using Python 2 instead but I don't have it installed here.)

Comment: Thank you very much for including the script to generate the file!!! I've been using this to run my own testing and was trying to post my own solution but ran into issues trying to learn Pyth (to compress the source) and personal time constraints (work and stuff).  Again, you're one of the few submitters that explicitly included this code so i'm quite grateful! Too bad I can't upvote more than once ;)

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <strike>9458</strike> 9447 bytes

Inspired from @Daniel H.'s answer:

> This code is completely standalone and requires no files or inputs.

```python
s='4Uq.(iAK%7?,JQ#m[([fERMx ;E^I1MuQ+<A*Mz"$v&[pp_,9-zr*a_3HNCN)l(*p(5;:.*b/?Q7_+ZdZS;s@2qfqT@H7<{29heKpXc5* !^n90|h#cUjg0B)t&H eQ5^j9~0Mb3`S92rppYosUdE=fZK?wTnb 3_|Iq8Oh,:p>HDIQ!8IqkoB=zW*arn7Z:Z3!a"]]b#=kK<+7+QztZ;#1>@k?8*p_["xbY Zk! E9S_32Y*QlDIJIJ9qzFoGqXrfHa4$Avky|tL_D?^X!sqmNXgg^I+C/8a;#Qc%:H!X"l%)SG)Mr; 1>@5<eJtj|Pmy:UkBDWXH>65oRqII/&1~(G!]n$ ^]5OMnM["qGoOVqSY)U$^%"^K9JG)Lk29s?"T5Z)`/3p9XF@Y{!*n1qESO.81cmc*tA3t U%/6=Q-kO8QSYkgzoQuoY3>u{Jg%5D8LrPQFumnWNr_/T`"V(_-e&_anzS+1Gsm5)Z"Z`#V/jjbYcJ%!;g)YH/`Mu5Qs&p8sW,.yj5o)?tg`$#k@mJs33`KJ<-$!u5QT^^rcy0@H} ksf^J^+ngy^f#xbH)[SlVC`TFkAN|Mx>$%|*x ~I;LO%skQ0ek(3wlm[Y2cG,?wl5Uel<oJ!Ci^ahw!b*;M__%YAn~*`|<[+*4x"Bjb@.D9KG&G.)S6`Fk{Z8 3p<ac!xjjK#@`L#`:I:)q4YAXqb1faD}`!=35oq~JdtXfUyBM#)cm/1N1[kST.iGf zvEg9_GHs_pRAz9;(azjob.+K!n%szh8`<,J&!,OqH]c3iad?4QKQ&lseRpssddIdca!%U]+J4RQsTn1l_O @i}%lun^>V/Z&tpO="=c7=upTST$1V:"V*7OjkZIN"UTKgH0Mv1%srn0JXfogu3[vDtl?ySk=uU;bjv5ValNCu+bu5q3N%Y`8Pqf1fX_wMLg:CqKD/m5Ng`,FXwey&"/]Iy,WhgY%tL%2R3rc,i6@>Z,i}#sj|5NqY IDsv+{cSL)"XF)M$%-/56?qj,YnG&hkZ*J#e1Z`DqOSn*l:y&IY}+o^NKPK0`XfSZ:E3Q=qGp7Qp/8nXRKP)F&kg:P$)jHD&chd%&`rtYx}cu+|{6~aY8CdPsy&OouCFKES!rgA~qB>"$;??rS*O4rAzYDM@H5HCrlpPonAsr9+RF-]{tp4pi}_)p/X sMcl]|/Ek(pmTS)T"mOoQTaJJyH99ef} (p/"YqoJC> 0@KDHi`50IT/ ^,$dlLZ3}whg:R?*ij;&MR|th^EOHj@dD&jo|eJ`O lnpq$`WXvVX2<m?wDtn?";0;v1[Cj=8)Ip<1]I-+u `q` %Rh^K?(iluL3&C?,iz*m^Ermb8r!1n4lLt%AYc$I7`v";Ir`?p8-[VJXl|N6UNEs-QjcP#^a}E`6N+.+0g[IJ;%393aazD6WOZQ4%Z`U=w&Cy1|GrK6-f=L`Fr,3sx9[B) IV8@EP.E+RBHJnK7sJv3`hCPeZJpEpt/d^bZ"jw: z^z8326&ZVFcMdbdp56$SO%rme9+_h"4Yep67C(:h+^)0.3&H4_1no>u {L5fq/l5Nc0^R94v0f`XeX`OL<3@ilp&;sN@?G6M!Au9Bxb1`_`p+| z)R;GIO`8}@`s*0!@uls7KS_<6m6+TO0U^|mHlLTu<J6e8{-vSFo_(hc^[_a83yNT~WpvZ5NT^(68sKcO2 "p7]^winJBK-PY&p#O7yIAP9X*D=e.2m+N&aNgZ#okHgEo"v/H>Uf:h{l4U$(bdxKAC"Zi39m@t:+ 5q0<(4``J`ic|!o6LLD&~p%:?S#~C1eO*_rQ:L&1*p!b6O_Hu-mv]Bsnf;LNLP%QmIJt6HeehR!^E"o!JB<+y+6`:$u,8qo[BM%2$tt-Qh+!Zz!w~5,73I&Q*m++!qol_,O_uw%Up^a6:|!;6^!u.6Q.dEP&rs;[6z! f"14gTUt-e0Me&%"t:c"!5U_v]3{dk?hNt *mHKDP| :L4%rmiJ,Ngk!)[0S`/4m3V8kxQt-"$KHEA%WK"W[MzL*,hpm!|(Pj+isOb`G5(m>sdq"8f1XU<V/l`${M9J``00Ts!*9zVpVb~ LJu*3qXIfFvtJMkt"`lF0TZrS9WQ%-@F)/JKf0:0:,9u%]Oqp<}rt!.5pe/N]m{5h>/eME0?45X2{IzHh?=t3z0q%<9IUv|pWS4egV@Elc)l@62+!gFJ?(9jfMUOi9H?9 2+L<n4_NWJ]*et0QOWaid06zJ1c+"*ANs49}kWYjA7.,tT0NM&PnK%$[Nolr9ad<U4!%h9%$:$m]8ts`h4qXa#pu@`1LlZ`F%ss@latE}M^p_@W^[5PbDpt*SqHnB$fh=U-]I%U*sos+S1$Mkn]uk4kIls?.e[m$h 0gz2R h]w}|_}io9YWMqw$Dc0|fI"AHqB@~j=Wot$UG6@C.#xmO_`mwak]UtqN*5xoF26E;fVyT*5V%eIgq1:Ka2/YA]nP%Nr9:s4S{`Hw]_@!;:*gsD<|- Wy1dJiT+[Y,O|H @ ;OIbJ35[-uVOkql8&_Jqq(t)6U`u+16}{!#p#UdKeGdjK#0eO~ E|@Dsp1J?QudA{54[C(cP0669O(1nht"xK<5NK6E~*,bk?"`W?apc].kFZ3buI^_A5<62B+++qM >m)5J`*_A6_%r%]uG4>ej:10f,04?Vd&6I~f"**cu9!e]uC[meIcV__c/y*!=n!5n,a`<JoYx}@Ek9ns8w+TWi 6T;$u@NjZ??4A@hM"<vAuEz=bK`adA0/!W[i7TNVd_RmM>5O9+CuW[A#%S6&3ty{QKgYo{Y|49Z?rfw?J{3NH33oodHFWV@q%0)kE}qsj_=c`vZ:r`of.Ek6]|xZ-xj2[Mmc[(}8`wB#b%Fu91Tqnmh;ZItNEi-C&_Th?=.vmcnN2~!ZYy*&FZH=3fW6eioEpsp+nh1*:a8jpLs25#^Jqa!9`8UCpmX9?s>8IA[F[ ,?e, =4SY&,o7Imv^$f.K (mH}%RS1g(}771, eaj/Z_~tML0<t3tZ@5H%k0c6I:8]ou8!$nb"sD0,mBUTbZ0q,JPCtD 86j"AUt)`6I}S+[_7o=o;.]ppIkrmZ2H=t6H#%7e8(WrGlN"`c1yUqy|A#s79eB^I+@biErY`j|^%LxVJ[~ydO7[ZKEPu()`i,dK$D8m10{v]&&Aq_Y<SqN[me5<JZ~4^/=1X6zZp?#g*t(>t&e97u3lqJCO%q[>o`:JSF^x_tN^(Z-O_44xSdFA)!U"]+(Iht$vq:%~<6M^TmNrgpt)XtHH<p%XC%z[qI!5^"B=1$tR~Z9-IozXvL7OKf%~f73UqM=3=n3I&7**uEWbL4Pu|./O"T0i0s<7"eIw~p61?l=x(Ku]{1wU_JLHok?,>tq[*L)_"ox_A0)/yK%Hba{jWt%2~u:wGtCZM8b>(Yc`YuHW$$abGJa]XeSEJjPj:l5s_&3{qtfZjuA.%jrQfTucgnf<WmA%h3lvb:_`mZ4f0s{04-d,2o{u}fXPFbs,<L3wN_!T.^T,w^][_$pk[iaMVqKXeU&xl<Bb`WWFIj_;>*:Lp0@Mq4TP8N79AeI}=e^fAjiz}aVGMo0,LtJg#.[=$+@upRCo@*K[Yt<zzsjaYpq:w%X(JNta8&&dq;OVLPz_T6 R:!;=4sisfsrh{QE?REQDNnx?~fc!Xj) U%Bg:Kk]l%,f$4KbD76b3jeUBbu(PtjRmtNX4p4NL3[c>c:oRU,@W3s,3X(z[-j!uNYfjqv~p.#1}T1O|3I`Tm=/|jC$Pp5T@K^bw^hkX%1?JlO,!D9"a,Z_4-jeV4;xeF5n@6UFt_Ge`lM.QtN]c+NRY3SBX69<R$^/j`6(BK*_,IO$Y;+($o=+"dP*x 8TCnYWN+1B4:}P ;0YmOCQE!;8_d?"Z3wy@EnRBRCMk&"YC;E$c60@1$Z#cID&w%yY]TYXK70x,8>ibSio6%= LW|Dr[ 56dy4fVIh}T"3c,CKxn[&a%sLQ7m&Qow"n>~eY#gtZ1<)wVC/U`o,*Y51Pq"1Fbm<8nY@oK_G04tie37@$ty+#Ha4}6#g(T(?_!^*+t#sMt"UUI!BGVPH5%`WP1o)}2XS_Q$W]o&@f;K}j;.*&Ow~1 5DjZb)86Ot@kJlLt5Fc%XbJDn!7m["4Tg~Aey6B<`Gj9(P[2w|_Y$Hv#ieWIOX%P=bmc#Ifb)e@&@9,`lNdtwn"`W39sxu/JiAx3@B6l9X[[>PH%r=}Ev_0JlZQ5V/2svC-Spm1jx"l$(_F4/9XdpYGjd9a%PS}iQEz#BU(KX.U%ZBR$&eDa{%!3S;R6of0n_FMc1~(dk`mb[g8^ 0H;:`4 )tRj]VyRTcp5QsQkFf"e|*%Y)mP5`4h9q+F;zR]r/,]rhuit$hQeLcS9>kgP]M5rw.:!>BK4Z&cot}hIief/9#drySW`oz 8U<P61W{IF^b,X?N5O0Kak~gik}S7fU*mdG8+I:qs,W@5h`5*ztYfN Bp+ru92rGb-O1+092Kz1!3s#,mB1XT|bEeOD-)2)ru3fJ8EPhp)o*+#vgZaYE,&Lwty1D/!%1UAO>_yQ2+9OZfZn3T]O?4p;.i[tF;/h 1d>~*JnVKb!>/Oc_peFyo5N/&VRu62jX!&a2qx4Y4,>=,(/"4uS)koV PW&50|3Ro=Xq0kV}31&B:luf$)"p>coIGqDq*G?DL9Ke =s8f$/&F4${o-w;%F"843r4690n+*4$4:"}f:Fgn@T"$q5K:S!SIVy[?APOmG9/%B)"U$OYtdIjSvz)Fr2Mk(5?ohx=dkC1/5;)fZ-D6MS;aYq:![FdI1DcovW-q@YvZJ!pA:y2A`D^%v?g_)x2$(wl%W;+Ks&zP}|~![;dO@lzLg;jotSF8FD 6g)^F87|JFX|JLL2%QBN]l~up*%AH6BT./FQu=QW0}q|``49Oa:ur/>RgB6KFC=1`T%Ge#57OOs,l9gvE-Os1C>[8EP[h)"de< VqpX}%L7O#2)`0?(A:ej/eZ_ pk_Q8F_+n:#ytGfqZcjg&.|gIDl{p$~Nf/]3a=$/s4rY<@)JZI:C@d>xetI4$z(WovMd`I499I_S7@yH6O}~N7&iqO( 9j*0q3$O_.=x6ocUdem.4Ln,NcBX+Af_l?ngmbG:^:Jo-dVM*jQq.#>E+Kz=S~Pa:~4oqGYO+"nCmQ.S+fK(f}.`ZE//&`s@${aEI&S4";1( uo/MT!<k VTeCV~t+1hauT$!5i[^:j&TQ-)&+e$aQ!J*BW~MajcKz-{1&^m$2ty0[kWp&|%5v}gl=nTb"LX;TVrZRvFmBo#TJ]GJ##v08F~mI8~IC|<4FB]p6fdFQc)d3_X?eKK^}zIk}[p^$+Bc4%[Jb9H$_gv+wuSde`5O;CGn")hl<[Y[fI6bnUvFdcHW,w,$wHk)1({*1_Lc49EtM"po)#z WSF+o;fU=N1`3:,%-.*^3vItGk]TnH_ `RyFsei$tSCZ!XY3TcmlDY%;FGknX_]?}L:?l#{#6{3q]cjf/PZc^swt}aE*K3.4z$aF|F.eFbzFmL_!Oo}n}z>OqDweNHw vU{tsTTl"58e/`G%-rCk(P=.+HlJG6U!3l@H)5b[9(`8B;g?&V$Eq 8p%V-qQ_?`?,V9tbS?#5#?7-q:C{+Z@Qv4n9Nnp"o4S$ RVqO"clGQ+qKhbv)_$*N,)a~Zii?t5^2u87"p@1no"tpeK.0Ege1uD 60-NcB4hW5RYI1%^S%9frsO$(DJ2RauC"kAar$Q;pNIsgId&mWg(S:B3^u@[$U[%%?zoHl"12&EmTHgBEqE)e:1,SOu1[FO.P3Uk+!D23b)|C6#s>3/=Q/i6>P?oK`4aa:KPRF=p]0/A(ShI"*J#zFOG4k/MI$bsLJy?":_e(TX6D8SzI0M@i5I$=#3<Oo"}%ORYR0L4f%}u9L"}v!!j:5.HPQ>wj%<1Mnmw=u=uC4A|}h9|.5R@#rw)xT,;m"VDs^9k*u$ b F) %Ubtk}9qu)%Y!DD9tdfyL89r/x|"%J-/Nt( b76&m>br%jjhd-AFI,{4Svy]OoK]mSVv3RO6U(&_Z;> tpJ0(^Tmu,kz8ct[4J-$p+gsUPT=L$"#/JHw28W"IEUr0OH}ORYfro"d!Ynx$n/I."ehRrtR;|b?k!eear|RL@E|1:AoUd}DOHic1b<5noB*3FTf;6x$k#4nPA9}k 3ecHB+6i.3ps7Zaj =4^)k_2[D%>o6YM{kFI^o/b8OUm3a ATJqK<M_~dyg+T,k#y=*O(l5TI9`aDH6/9@5b5H-jzEqomM0e EF`RM:$S#M^9$d8f?Z;G=l:c:`dZ%Kjk@$xNneV~k/IV2*J[s,Xy#Z-=x_2%Ae^"8J-cIrp+r2B6>jYjv/>B#M()Q%s#+qF%g`h7J[!1f&pY12}@<mycmsGGXjx/+6"C?c21l@#|mYin>:j.n9p6M]ErsFpQo1x2cp>V3bAR&MUEqu!S>HAvElG;+Tn$"06h]Xhxz]EP0pO{"G{]6ezG*^;`Fo ~[#xJ4g"i"eE.,"gfDpSUvkYZ)ZB?T&P`EdUi:F=J)_fR2 d@,:vFMHEXOT7LNr:D 8zbGak*6frK=;&;r48#|VK=X!>e:qHSaP _@tzs3!(P]s{K8JLj}N=J4II+zZ}/o]y~`YDs/1lmEjochY68bpvY`8creixvrt$K=!{B-p4{JqN8Xj;EjovSF&aTHb>:S8/k(%jE+4_vj0[N(fi,_6K""_v"?u4H(J=C7dWFxWqQHEa(da!uR<B1p_8c=qt>-ie:>N--xn["^Oe]F/jr6ov?-*3g~p:]C5ZR*$[[qnUfY;F$` 7U1 yNK0W)SRXk]J`suGsNqIcpy#9,far1II[8sp-rRl3xN 99n,nKpar$=O5vM`U8;+Ro)Ou?][W5%d/Fppr*x1=qbM+zVjoi(UQM*lP@y^qr[!tM=j Ie$UIQ<<xco)#$J)SY8LffbpW:qa!B#:eN"U6 ,AZf8RlNcOp+4]2=Qt@D0]D1&c5IIEs%K)[~2-2 sIzjoDvegp=^;e74qFGs?,f#3RWObs;IP_E;am$Gk6[52gUe Zj[mLCPdOqX3VPbH`hjmb#W34}=Z8k3dU5:1Cw0K^9X NJpMW^Tk&kKR+MhJ>,Kk6(pox_Payp|tRz^$lVb&S]e/Ui[j~>rb0[Q"Qr?>}R,Enk, ?gp%/>v45j07Dfd*obC 7`:tRwmVZp?H3QDmPxi;I{a,b;Ka}PWu!_D_3|b.%;HieLBICQlVB`!%svIsGR!,N[J?.I<tJ0-rQ.&5z1hTmcmWWx]!@bS0:t0:|%T1m|l2,)caoP8C]/<ci4C:12X*He}^?~80QCC#z7:<(/Eu.9a_CehrQn2e0&bfbe!7%c&niZ8Ksn&uABrm~dp%U#!^Z$:$+RF6R<u<GpnlEF:61^]7Pef,e}+t4Mr!%&IgB1",j77qMdG+GM^^%F)3s>y5ygHOl3E1w2Y+v%$P8wB)X<wtt1SFuNel:U68H9vq KefHyQL`:lYr.r! GGe5Cldcsp[[u?%t@@e1Pp%&]3;EX+T/qrqUJ#riO@0(fC"Sq^YE(=P:!(%g0X%Cc.%4@ktLYl!/Y$fAD{#s6P0&w!/=3hPZp ts)9^+[Lam#f+O+VjN~wHa|8[p3"J6YO d83t ULds}k@&ca,q0[[<Nm4F>h=S&E"^1;Hcxksur9 fedGg(gJ[vIVRmKsm*gL!dh;FIFErpX5i`d"Q%TaY$v62Y6e4(U!w1WG+iaNTg&5jK&b.Cv` 5U&A#`ah.gZDh["[=x??I#Q:_W3>siAGL,J62y,{A)4 o{5g:*q7nSOkn{42VemY fLFhJ0T64Tm`7mt8g!<EW(|V80-{=[aIO%XzAIcwkqC8i77HIZQPJ#S]1V>wIfQO#S+xPNfkhR=-3i,?(p*_EJ%7(qbe}5x#$Flx3VN)!G.J88Kjq+=Fr`LwwbyZ]mH[sn){-@:`,tHCYF.;S/WE`a7H8N-jKmNE%_a!14dY|Q:2aty jaqXEeb3h%M%mri*{4dCD3}~*h.}`:KLSsj4Nk arjR)Z+(^t%Xo^+30)&d}?"C3g%tarrq |J$]2#w1C3J8C&H=G78 *__joovL93vRE3RsBLcl(^K>474cdZq+)bzxJBy2JboeD$+($uE>4E(=@FKk[<0wlTy~!STR31x&8NK}7@,Q9t;$e`X ?jnL+HEU ERMi1t#"u9Q!+Ak<<9.F6FPh(N1cp5Nfk)95FFAkh.go3}M7Epn*3_@?d/g|0z@lu5z~_Ug7+BO?t OJp./]%)|#^]AvA_pAJ>xIoi2PIn$0qbPABO"b:d|^$?Sr&M?bDzbnVXH6;h!C+N@uZ]7Ql*M]&AhDT_PxcrQT:+ (>~EuIDDu(qO8eMw`M{Pxo*@-fa^(9rHJ93;VdOph8V26cUXP5C:ub*QA!N0Hj9oh9HP)8]z*${pa+G!|<C9hl6N$!uRa >y1[l{s#x7l$xp9P#*85;:V&B%<j~<RHA{`F.daq;SRNS49Zb:wt-.zmJ?39u1>q[D(?U^x%<L~M<3Q*Lp{sLg0CJ=+]cnF^Dn)q]?|qk=[.){K+B3P5pn sBHC`=iCmT1C ^r=3Ub2:i9LFlA-p~0feW@(${OE380<8HR%,OpV+?y^ NYT5bPhq#Bs6N+:5Z^Po/WO:`c^eu/~_~GA]8OTFhYTdkg&Mv#G,qLSK~ew3L0N`p.C9LMwi<V|0X&v@9vg5=y+`u#uJ?%e_ov/,(N4dt%b_85ftQf)!>&,]n1g<cD"K YM:jfSUWle6Mc?;g&eAo!HNzZzi/LLp^&^H`227b!^68~G"ee4=MU5WG@6%[4)g:B{5Fb5KGn/(uehYf{Pk$J~g-iDrRe3K@[.-w6]eCaA"fxH4.KRN.yi0~Q2f3"6A_<j%PBhD~EA?>y;:xz0I~,>Wy7mPpo]r]T+f@kU&1LTqTv0,{;7J!1-$i*LW@4tH(8lT^j%rq+g,0+onW{:62Wg [DPJ~v|N-TU-@:z)oy0 g^6`w]>C9KH;en~#9UPUUS;2+e;HG[{sWo<P:d0;q]s_vZUhvXym`%qrD$]ryXY^E>7V<"N;/5`2 ICTP;]57/$ FUv!MP=#:}k+]e~"C"&>$T-+K%$oY-+?kFXmudc5ync6yY5^Vx[f[li:P`|6bdiFS8:r@2ipe1ciq5,+dR-ZOmq%J$O_=t7f1Ugt3/=`|q0M;:O7Pc"=th+N?w3o u~3oXzHW$m,2n0ZD3>d598<a1R$+X*MEce            '
D='ACGU'
Z=[c for c in map(chr,range(128))if len(repr(c))<4and c!="'"]
u=''
for i in range(0,len(s),4):
 print(end=u);u='';q=sum(Z.index(c)*93**(3-n)for n,c in enumerate(s[i:i+4]))
 for _ in[0]*13:
  q,a=divmod(q,4);u=D[a]+u
print(u[-3:])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TZnH1oLqkobn@yoAga1iAAkC5iwYMCeWgiIYyWDWWz/9n@5JM6XCB1W8Vc/CeQZH2yL/8x@/8C81dVPRU6WDZEsJcRgx5ahsNEa9B5BrbASiFw6xfCXee0HwDZUdR0lwyZcX3ypku1/rx67RuBOlc3wqvkuXhlkFW@1X45xfzriGOym3s/l3hjvqHWeh0XEA3Fgc/jlGtOn5gFdjAdoG9CG9OXM/vLcj1TGX8RxnafvTfaNgrDql@8TaAaTyEVxWOiZ4p9iuC0OQFdyLXS285vGtZ2VX/IoEt9B6vYsULp08lsWGr2CVixDF8qXExh1Fhh67JbC6gECDGytkZhkfXuuCKIic@2raLXfhGe0tBVdul@cn6Cr10mYB@q7ZXxwOGwGrpdltLjLUEL4NLqArEhu3Yj0vB/yFp/O6GJw/A/PJTy/V@nzRLjK0PXIFIY0Sv2gLXFswsFnTUs/qyZDbsqWZO17GpvAGgTYdTmzFupcM55egCb2KqWnS4RbN8vINxi3CbYylFEtophYPKmQATJE0UxgmLxI7HC8vh5c9DO0lWQzf4gGh62zXGwyboWnN@56SnqjQLKokdVTZWq8xRrR8k46toJUamaXP591SExEwd4gt22m1F9JDH3VYf55IPc@0HSsFBxWOXMqm6JOk2hHzSRj8s5lsNp72xMvtL3DxjY24wazDc2NEHrt2TB5fZzV10rxU@p/eowgjn/gD@Am5roT4lyGuX6Lk/WrKy4zWSpTuV3qqX/O2CNZOm@3xDu7iuZ6iIMuK9Yurn7yMxakHVD3vyqk612mhrVRszKjNy3vFAqST32rg43zuRMpqN6LyAh9zqWVl4e4IY1v/qmCBpG33J@6DhTF9VnuRmGamiT4hX8aT1KllAK9b48AprbavOKPKi8tFt6@zvUthHdBC/NeRVfMJEQUTkttea@Rpuy9Rw84Qvfr6yPH9/V7Ya1sQma4xkRoN/YlFXBUJKJ@@yDW0NsVZeoUGjlSAClq2EDqT8QQmZjw0i2el82Ul9KHppHNo470bgfiehYsLwz6EpHyrB9fSc3wphNPc7nyjZ9trvxZiu5B2yT6yVNmBaxDGQrn3uge@5nbqaZPuH9REc3HXnyiUXgvPxPx4WCJBF8mMSE9LnJhycZU4fSP@@UP33SUg1P0b9tbG3Ri0aMZ6MJJM00zJPSeWVgs9XlZxMaITK7XuSmMrfuWfqLD8Yvam3xl0cHVhjFd8gxwW3JaTHTpp1lqMOoNYE70c@AEcO7frqHbcI6jqBcvHVwuxz5v5bZdsbT/wn6hkh7VmpzEGvUPl51aLEJwrlbxxXKK8ymtZ75XbdLvmXZ2BbVV8j8NGzeT6HTiUc/oqMSe9APyedl1/0o1L1DEn49gEMiV7ONmK4rPNcbrxBaJOGlq6tlgrAni5U2@fVBoXJmlgk4D31@6K/N6PB35Uip/OObQ3@gTHTUNqn8v7Onq2P7qoSsDVclxYnS9us0Umb5bu9cAqQTk8dyPk2rnAxgQnT6yFJBYCqqsCyOi46ZSip2vYJdFaKXF6xc1NwzN3rAcSFnXtBkhlqcFCVr1BOcFTSw6blGfi4vrpM9N@w08Oz9ogstl@GyrTx1IYfpAFMYeQHLndvurMXFoNKWSlTgt3tPYkPi2vwySNQldtegnSf3ByNQYIM7bcGKQa2KjaFq1O1hdvpHqsDfSV6DScIL3f7FbQ@c4Dr82LJTMMupo1td5@t3doBh5LiGfqHKYcIWqpO0y2FuWP2CaGp0i0TSmEZRdD4N2lDTd9pfsavhlx1A031IW@UKVuniyfrg6a8/vlUovpgZWQqz52hKqoDvYBXrFRriVIKvstq34cB8vh1c92xkqeMRlsIuHTzcdsX7uTMC8yOvtO3sZNW4ketY2sbFny2Z/85s5tRfcnmyjD@h1NygCQk11v7idLrHaSgyXqRKTsU6gMuEW8XtBTGRPro9v@YRWxL@1Dw4Zu6XZxavDH95WawtHd/tGp1KDVieTMcsBjAO3i@SilqqJ60j6gzXS7dfTnIHxpHPnVCF2KK96Q76JE3AF3jKS0w6R5W1d9y8h1@90BMjQFMWDaun4cgZsGZINiNY89MUbl4TDBurZc7SEZOAiSwyMGrl7g/UcnsqSADuMmhoGufVUSkhLekamz2TL8B8wxGzBMMcPUvjFAPT8nMy8QMCCCOkymQVLHezqKQAGvQSA9VW5r8r2/lI79AIib7U598AH4LvVXzJOY6B8uYEzGx2qaMskZe3kMgyQEd9qNCjLvQHO59@rGE0fHBD/RwRk7@dJObdFRs@jvXYg1iMU0P0tfVfjd40RVxfGJD8a518yZ7X5AVwzjpLsQjOYtEHuXAFKvTXyy8sbcfIgky81YWuwYOI/zCS5E1pLr5L9eAKZoR0/31@abPhbTeq@Blyh6kXkLr/axVAjIF@4ieU6Y3j7OfEzph1m5cdVi1zKTwcBDUyxFubPRm0onrl3igAzWzVuU0p@L67ge4ENpvj3tceYlEhoGxSt9n@K@l/nyXMmmEsEE7/fQgdVBYLlvXz1uu89PKRA5cgjMw@aaDXz1SLmLbcQJyyrRva7UJuL75es2aHx7G0cpzzcyPdjVnSA@dttWFTaOhWlyLSDTuG/72JiAexdrHV6oi3D1SyldNuEjgB9emRFwXN@/H@V7srnlvOfe4bqGfwwBqrTdavl3LsztAJ62mHItFXmYkqKa9@1lPQ3cfpx@2M0M08gZs@ckTs8QXTi4BN/ZZtLLytoaIH2P431q/Fbb97VSBnN8/ODX858kMH8Se/E0weRlQvq0gTKQk4SdSNJyMpxJF/fKooroutEgxkzVECOY7xuMOJHpvqO39n9TFNelH9D4lOu@Q4ilYbivvGlKrkW1Ac4wnBQlrGMAPTp5ut9hGr94YncpQeq8tHW0derSXJG7UNgoFTrPZKoYhrk9oGjGaFGNKxVGQTxkHbaoon7mCdxI4FRptkcZ4WdA8bgWcqC@DmuyqQvaTFG09DMOFiyQthJbNS/af3Ok3Lhwls/escn8BDCTHByW@@dVqURVyscelL9VwsarsOuo230FT4Nz@ZSd9Gd7ZWT2irTEYbVwLlciyJhByeD5HnYOS/u9/FDcquQZ95L4JvttkrTtfbs5n5VdBI9dGl/XPysFTb2teE@1jVTjwqw/j1Xycc7IPVOTo19WvVcjO6QZcsTEtcxjbiUE/cYpWUOVyV9Xp26mZvUzP3C1fMbR5qpdII05o5/shuM7mHUk4vyWPTtdP0NHNqK7BTmVndYcc8GV/CIrVOSmDCRKegIoUOMlmrCzgnnbwEaqA0TN9hcZjYlD9JvNEglA357TK@UX9Lp4PiCDVZluIxdcYwSeXdshC8LWDvLreMKsTie7Fe4mxEEtqAMsc4Yq0yCmMsJ3jMlK1i7YudTacYSLZ64y7cKftEWQrM5G517r2odUjXhO3eenEvGznF7924XLu1PDW6rnzwbpPmai/Hvupay86jQGYTSmnhL7DlxnTQJ/39YoWnGVZX7s9v@qTOfF1Y/apAvEgnmtnFLkEA@ixQDVuWxIXl2xJiGuXLRVXhw3Nw8l6G@iq6SkUNRjvG9WYuAUWmNR4RjAN5dHfnmmt5mYfe/gBLFF0G7nHWRRQ16yK4D0BqoWCDgY/VZcUrBfi1s3K3UM5GdkyanbK5AF60@Os/F42JjvutQg/KTSEjTBT7ifz0K6cP85DFG6Fh7RTrh@E/epInbb9qWUKAauHO/GFMh@KBU8ln52kPZu@z7PAyTzC/l7K6iteuyuGF1q6jJsz2F4u2uJ2/VCHzfE8@DMX2lfQcm3Gxirc1hJIWdvaExC7WAZ@blZQY7k9bbj/0RhRRm4/8ap5D6Rsd/h11gMmjs/ke@S974CTlKbSeK@WcsK7Fzk07Y3czsLfYo@rvnqTp3Pm8JZyRXjfNfByz2XmgzYfpar6MK3oG@Myvn0@m5nrZ6NJ7qBeIik5AKMlUNnVLPL8Y68DPKvl3/eLh2XvyOLqNgPtiyK7t2cNOsOXsqEAUY8mCtQ/sk3fO/4HjZKo8aw3rcepZ@hgYtz7I9Tqge@c1lfkYQBU51dPcvsyLM@re7C6CA4j8ygv6Acqt8lZa2o8fZomijPST9BLqIvOXkGw/7SOLu3n5OKEN8JIX1IQZ2YhfTnXIMHDj0pdza7@@Z4WSBESbxKCbDOQdvESqGSZ31G5R56k7bKzLQZKC1dvfZSw6C/1rD@aEmOqwuGy4/gTfqsMtFqJ64kBAle5rAobBcwaD/4oxZ2UrOW8z5GVCn@OwBy@NKUasMGmGOVfQlakfdnuWGNqqNa74JCy1quAWsMXibgVUQT6ugdeS7Xk@Wik8UfCbZ42o1PNoMUgO78U/dkgGb2T8qYCcfvBCK1RK3zsGR0i/jdYdZEh/Ydsoo/fRk5BCsiH7vPaumpaifiS5oYuBDR3Jl51lqW7Y7SwqngpJPZMhw8scgfuX6ZyCE6iZYUcBPHgojfC6DpVACrrdmgTSPqfEDYsW9mMVaG8Hxto2Uj1/mec6k4Kt1/BEDXz6tdjGWkoHwR/7ZXuqkhi51Yt8CsKUPU5PCr6E@mmldbZy46kDP3j7KE27fISZ8L0gIZFHamFhGMXUwvo2UuoV77@@Bu/c0JkvMfYVo8VR5kucpcuYUsFwdtxCt8GzcFF6@rIT1LZ/xbLTl2TOL8gK5wVGlSaW6xd5at857bIoPx9zRsvCLVabSzSE2RVXUEo3p9@0ZAcpwbMbaBW0qzp/3B9v6imjv5wG4AvJ3jVQqIBaPzevYcTTTnj3GHl6YB6Z84soyZA1qljpyLNXOv0dpLJ9beMTwF8HGod7UxV7wcBuse7d1TPFisdqgVqtnB9yicdCPNRfbeczxX7RfATvMDhpi/heZml1iU@rSEd7aX3@F0@Y6zxjRu7lssJvCun5iX6aNKx1/B0ugDVQfzQi7jtXZJicBwLtN5ESDpR/60mlhMPruGLtWTsUzMC0lDZBuDoxOz41jkdlhtl40E2r0HT6KeBhFiWpGKynOYwThpZawscrKWSpSTS53koJlLHwFiX/zFRWvW2YHFtKQpjt582nQ/jc5GIZM5L0B0m3Ef1JJKFAuJaBqiwnHsYs@AwRyl8Q85sgsLF7/MviSBVvlraMAxyClqttBy6268Vap3uY4OFHzWgNNok4LfdvKeQ5oQS5EexXC49cfxMMVDX4NvHqzyBIJdusOPwbEwe8qlykAyW1waqcagKSwtg71wHt9esaaX6V2idMk@Pgr7S41I07mYsUrWmd44t126PCg39wJR1@zbPOmWl7eVCDoV/pmpqPUNcisdlNgjA0fvV2Sewzo@@hp8Pz9Qzu2l8vXVPeTOdjBuss06wBximyab/YjNxUfsdjPIsNpfX3@hE0cqbaY6SaWbw7AwnONf96OqFCdt@dBLF0eHKtNp1gqEOkFaeoTOSpKfuHKHWyMp@UStKP/VSz7GoL2eB2aus/gif8MnkompeCla4fVzWl8pgHNRhmxTwSw@8gxahrvSzgc09TkI9evbgX99I70mtwU47VPeMl@OiSuBr5X3xYceCBT8is7tW2@vChTHCco4W362Gen762fRkytFAe4cx10SlpRU4cHY2nSvmymqayX6WnWBVQzlWrIO5q7Fb3jRTu5nvfh56KYixQbWeRXGv8GW/1G221pKGGTVzGFqjBmdqPFNqatGOo2qfhl@bxsCOqagHBEFQjvdm4D5CzCb6LXZL8CI4zacwCB9kjf8GZ0MkzEU0@HtEBTj1fmvtz1rnVfyTaAbE84ET1y@zB30g9C37@FasCY7qLvITWbeanRrmlU7MhHXLTESueFs82cK7E@offJUs7p2GGPfHGqxPaksSnqns/m@hMtXdjYwVtUoRBZ3XBtWDjfsHo73ukpLuVrLgmLHa15eyobA7KzprbnX2vPEPQHf25cYEX3HCaWrUVwj6EGOHYu8gPm4idk5Y1roEyrJJ5BkKr4hb0LQuqwnVlsB1NGz6esnOBjXVuBiSU4081pfIrlm62ItlHXp2@VL18g7wrxJd62djfRgpW38e/DdNuIdMkW94G3z00zpzd2raXYVULK/1vdVlNz6Xe@378Bt@g78yeQK0ayeVltI0qtdooNCCmtfxRYzBclruR2jdzIXVdlq7lBCZ3DDBVgHmSXdoVJSS4kZF@zGpQgdKWWTLl97Y6vy8EZZXN9yIJsaw8Bo5kqQdm0NMbdz3N1iChzvJ2Lb3@p0KgX0JhOyWcgpE5YNBY7eSeGNg06Ef58OnvzrJuo4p0dLgUA2Y4QzPF@Co3UxM9qGNehS2XrwMOf0Bf8g7FFzfoiO@Sq5CcsyPJURpPSy21eIyKANc9I@VBtuI6bzRGIshYTclFIDcnrBwHqG3MU@NSbiF8l0YZg@McVBye6o1HbLdwajZsFZ4@lKdHwUoLgYeTWlFnVJ9wR453fFZwniFT06WTB1dvwS8F75RAtwIULmJRv6ItJoOcK7lIF8Q64LfW8geObpVHswLN7PSJ7oWea9EBbCGlX5fI/cJ0WPyhHvHntMEjkTmtX9DXeJhzCwA5oxAJnugsuXc8MYsgTrdS7YG88uy3npxwdCxGS6H0SBXZZBzeLOQ87n4z5ZaQqJNzW@PdeS3Vmb49mNHEnMNIoqq1wRCBwRj/6ttmHi8mK1QKbEJOxgB386mBS6MBRJi@17hp1DQmPq4VL7@/cshmdDe3BpPWArLaQg/TjyglHusytdQF3fep9Rt9z4EHzFnu6/dal90ohdnrbsapxsTowc84AvEcoaVP4AGiB1rV3FmFOKdPzsanv@45BN7KJk5DpStJll731pChs7vWOlqUlugcpEdDv5nvLbPw/YJHGJPAtxKXqlJwKnbuttJs2V6R3dTp5fDdc2e7gONJrqqMfD40hvw8F71iitcq3Cldd4db9COudLGX70LX32u6SFWSYuyn5i8YyskoWHkkEq@gZixaQmeH8DNFNliufl@ZYuViO9aGyI@BHMbSIH9ZgVZZAwUGdJZL7lvPnUTL/VWpwfaYyBaiUtQ1zLkY@5PFlF/pyyOIfprRue33SGNvHIaE5xRu4qI7Q3bbghOC62K7fGtZXDJhYM4cxxvTg@XuvGAHekN9R6rxn91YpvcmrTBn5y5CFSB@gE6Y1UAjoYdWc8vV2Wq9iqWpqgA7Wxn574ZkGMKcYoA@zLCf7W7LUbC2mS7fY9/g/OXrvW9hJnDK9TyKE5j2Ijn1mnsACLOu@2x9sBoJSDl0@C0cHaf3dYsXv@9gsiJQjYa/VN2@vnT13W/TRxNRtnWzsuGXbn3JYqq3n66XHzArhTAN/VpEO9RbfPLs65P7PbuIluJ@1dkR@z6UsUOTcwSrmdcbkfNU4JhelAkHKDSiHVjoqFWnY/bz7m7rDd2Eb3WzAc5auEo7BawQ2KyZPOF/vJ5N9OC20kfd1Mnz3GvpWScfLwc/h1jV6N4rAsu9bUWOaasApkpwTw7HfweWw8WlzWouqHLb/vCprzjHAJY@sRgiCzvpP0Rlfy0Qc4zkpYHedPXQoSfeupUzaHjeyYFJbW8pxG9umm43jxB1Fwdz3sNTvbp@h02ItfB@XnxvVkMOgVzoCgw1NhmM8/tD@dh8XYeMl2DWPnzPk/Hq9GeL0PTRkgUVkZ7Oja1yQHo9aZwjAo1/F1nUA1WhAaPtKJyb9MMgP4wuts12/6wSlscnqWcpstv5QwIuRoLu38nDBQGrmtCbcujExnDlMdWJ1ls1sb7CV3Qc4Gu7Z6PJu7yJykvoUVeyH3U5onane8s@EWQF90evPN5IJeOiOsdxSLic6FiTp//DnYPp1PMHpt4Otsh47Xenp6ks@/orfD5SE09ErF7yjRsC4JoHRwkHTxRtFnPFs39nF7VwOyKh@M7ubsD8Pb5LBuDh6nnPDeJna5zvY7mIegUlfIzy6F5NonvVsVasPrrKqCiH8T/NYITPRlsZQS8oGIJ71hCqVfxHFiauZ8/liD5d0Y5wOc/yATwvxcM4mYtrUHbG2dzmsnqsYTmUW8rX83pR@LD2u1yCvL56PpRpjitkpNP3pDK6Pj6M7Y6WAW0VDrtGI7voWGlapn/vYOMo2AmxXMw9ioyYzyYb7lWNdGk2eIzTo70I2E/sUCqueBCCocqgSUOGezbm/fwlq9zQZpxki/@KSfh7Z0JRvEPbPEbgg8YO/V2CJ/DwJi3Az7@pWfMmybu7lARzfaz2FX5a9LL@WBQKul07XrXvMdWQ5LSFAu68TAQdA1mWsssEna9dypGPFOUhmPGjVo7G6WjWhhwINR5IAvkJqWQqjyJegur2B6CRuV@jviMwMcvYPpAnkcrBwg8GPcBpO7WzNiYBI2O/d/9/b2w8oOCYnMUgL27H9/BXb3/vdSRrVtwsVlOd83qWbxWBijDWhD5Nra4@KHHgcY@r51iB5E@SbMRmbHN@OHLrg/5ppCs@E5C/qk7qEhMtku4RuTWTI6FZ2Cd2Lewk7b/uSA0ucOukvVbipAT9FKRN0eU4dV/ShDcuFRKgmRIa/MyaJ/qrS6CZHJPBPvSowC7Dd94ONu1hpLF@tNZWa6uQSMbvMo4hOGmphq1gzYA5hvzKOfGYsn3wV5K0jI4lURtPvFrbGnbLYtrIYDMTJeE7PiXTCGUmSMPQZ943IcFZLkKVGKOnGlISLZqLvTv/QjAjevD3LWj4GtlMiynbOLFZqe2r3fd8/V2mzLvhV7J8u8mgjatWUzlRun5w11m22z/eS5Y/YbiLIFCWq//Az5zDZ4Auetu2joO/KI9BDTO8Xf1L5WJ7@/@DH1VflOd@yfqf4F2HrnUWyFRTcBsrA3GInH0P23BNXIAxJsPc8FPiK8zkTuRI0U2RraLrSyLBBXlLNt37oceRs1yJFf7WrX6KZTpLKUtl@5WGz3eojVZ0bc2XodxqJw2ChSf21UbnYuch6/XyfPHziejEjigbL9zjdbTgy5IAfr6gIona0u1m5MgcaodyKCCBRyQxCrXPJ5LtVkmoNjtE/8wfDfm4xxdLNZufyV1Ca/vWzDseKkUi7t04cP/ipfQ/r1U6aHLFaVSgEgiU4qvUZin8hmXblVFKciFh@CfcoMBAvG3d2gUpWgHb//bODS2EN7pV39tbNmizaTO4I1rF8OV@vs8BrvrdHKsT5RBg/NG054DIgWf41QqNfDqCuxeu@u9t6Dhx0vJ43tJsp5bZEjc7O95BzZWYbRposBXePDXXxYAft4@8zZR649iLHrVxx@O1usBX7yNe54Zfrw32jaAsUnIV/ffuSRvcIPhxtE4iyd42doFcmff/lRu/JWm6n91s2NR/0xxa12/D1Ipl6mWCK5kCi6cj1amm4eSL776@XJYbzrvP3uAa@JBWytWc1N3Yq569LHvRTkVOzdwarkgHYswK@2a2rhVDMnRA3YeAVyusvwJ67bvFaSzg839Hk5Cr@lBsniebY9QhKSM8NKzw3QX07o3eDoRqo@08d4erUZ2Om5xKvaRg/TP@XXqqxZadI8Lif7ywHt3SKthNsdd376nezifdVJ1bhu737Kzz74Ar2VuduBLjwxNYyEYgnRFfuWTkT71D5AdgpLG8HQiIFFNLG2iENeq0MdYNnjz8Z4Or/qTE8r5Q6oXrHBdv@1ep3S3a6zQTdtNZPJ7sANw/5akK5Thd6UnrfKDCJTsQNffdPNHd1pWeloqB@XxntwgcXfIXmqeyOd7JTlVPLOrPXatgIZjzaV6oz6qecJ/w0zBgkxFSV/RgbVY/3XqJSKzxz/eOHCL1GcP7PmwLHX3nqCGeXLFCW6E3dywxPvXFYEiSR8infnZSpoR9nrZHNGPBc7JHDMtuZvnsnMD4BcH4i/26efnEz/ROAVs584cNgw6n1drHGddk63fhFuOphOx7kMpufaLfntz@38gN/jOXftK7fV9HhbPE0Vcb06vPaei@WmUczO8lA/l6bVDCDUJoPcms6mYaA5vYG9QSHCfy/YWv9BNQgtwpMk1kFge5nESpfmwgz3Gv20NOa5pDezh2zI1xM/UD/Mbn9qjlneK2dOjk5oJ5dOYPtRciWZLiL@MX0hyBrE9BD8AZH6cfFejpeyAw0qBEesX7qTNhD@SHvxas9hM5Gx8FWdLO5pjs1viRGMLeK9hqYD/@/695964d9KrTX9959VQdYAw/YADThZgLl1otrRS3hb66BHiQwbi50M4KpbUU93vKgWi@WprbUHNLAA/Qut/wkL//77z3@9T//1/j8vPPFfez@WoGL8P4Djnawgqlv7QhjL/dc85xb80IyuUidrrz/@QsY5Mh6Pkkkr9t9AVuJ/D6Jboal720CP@vKJP/1tYrHYP/97TuXvtoyv4wT5Fx1wE9vC/nQz7X3U/Uv4l6Eub9dY@M//5Q3lJMmvY//5z/8A)

### Explanation

This uses 93 ascii characters (`'` and big python representations are omitted) for a representation base 93.

We took words of 13 ACGU letters, read them as a 26bit integer and put it in base93. Each 26bits integer can be expressed by 4 base93 characters.

The golf code reads 4 base93 characters into 13 ACGU letters. The last word is cut by only taking the last `len(uncompressed)%13` (here 29903%13=3) letters

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 4515 characters (12265 bytes)

```python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
b="""ԃ㕄⥪ག ⠥ᬙ◓ٵ♀Ⱕဆᷟ❢ᯧ⇥෢ᢸ㑁၂ၒᶵ㈼⋍ɭ⑥➏➔⽖㚷ណⱡ⎈᤽ᛚ㽷ી㴌ἳ⥶⧵ᠬ〈⋚ɣᗩ㕒ཛⲷ⛒㟥ἲ᫟༽┘㏢㘈᥀ㇸ◟┴プⵗ⦂ᜈ㪑㝘᠋ᛱ㦰➊᡽⇔὜㧴㣂ᬏⅣዶ㓟᳈◷ᩝ⩡㟻J෹ኸཙᥭ̋㐐༹㷺Ӕ⾺㆐අᲔ㻋๟≱⥇̕ᠰɼ࢐ࡎ෷ᒫᰦ޷๐⼿㡈⛤ᶱȉ᧟⩱㹊♜㞅Êᙎ୹㴃▇≗᫂ɼ╅㈤೿ᴒṺ㜈᳡〗◴⋰ⵧ3⑰ឌ⊕ᰅ_‰ղ੘߼ݨŗᅚ━ᨐᠲᅠ⠿ᜀ〃◇㥑㽌ֱ❤ᨵ㭢“ނ”㩖ɦ܍㜘᝽〥⇸㋾ㅗᐎ≞さ㟢᳁ᜤ̏ẉॷ㔥ઠǧᝐőᶣ⇘⁘ビ㊜㡍◫Ĩၰ᧹ᰂⅥⴏ㟛≅㩗㏧ᷖ᥇ៗ⡂ͷ⤗㵨ⷤ㮐ℽᴊҏᵵ㳃㖬ཥǈਖ਼ᰄ⚀̰ං؄᝟Ვ”܌ㆺԕᾆᕙ㥨⃞ᕷ〧ᰏᗱᄃⅠࠅ㗁⧟ၕÔ‏9㞧ぅ㷂ఆħඦᔞոᣏ➛ᵴⱠᕦ⮉◀➘Y㞷ᕈヺ㤐⁉౼բഖৌ☗ޑ㇖ࡧվቂƓᝁ㺒ԣ㟝ᵣᜥ⸷㤉ș២ᵑ。᠊ⶥㅾᜌフσ㝌㕥ೋ㗼ŵTᦂ❹᷀ᝯἠט⧞ðԏೝᣈᙔ๝@ᕟ╷ṲᤘᑟἹ”Υご㷀⅝⋢᠏ㅴ⌃ᷔƣర৺ቡ㩤ê‌ņᙓ࿌ȥ⨣͵ȳプᥰɽㅒʅఠ⤤㜎ᵰ㦡Ὗረ㕴ᐯ㥇ល`ಈ」৞⥸⤄ᱽȂĩᢉ‾㷢₀㵉ᗷܢ᷄マϔ⃍㜄ᢕᰥ㇀㱜ဴ┇ష♺ᄣᜉ⽈バܵ⺝㗟⌞ᶄ%Ḋങげᒊׅ৾ጜ㟍ߤℤ┕㇍⟜㕀៥∑㑝ᥙચ౳㇃̏ᱝッ̵᳨ᠦĜ㑽ৃܔ⠽¥ἅὺ१➙ᠩッฌఱὓܜ፠‧៘࠲㸷༠ᣈतᘂŵ㏖ʘԳ߂ᒊ൵⌤ᜍきᔷ㔕%ৈ݄⅀ǣ࡝㰰㤀ཀਈ㟗ᐞກ㕊ᐈἼ㷗⏎━Ϥ␠ẇ⃗Ɯ᱒Ӥ␟ਥß㟓᝵ᐻ㈠᥹‰㙘ᵶ㺠ݐ‽トᘉ᥃෥܀ᕁ⎋͙ॸ⡑ᆎὅᗷ✪ᄡᥐ㍗ᴱ৖㢀ᶒᓧᥜခ♇ࠉᵘ๕ἁネ『͜ࠃۧౚဳピ຅ᄉ〴ʖ൰⌰Ȍ᱃Ηᵰピ₂᧰〤൩∰ɝቔᅲԇ㠙ᡨㅧ⢙ᵍ㈗ࡢᖔ̃ޚф㟷ݝᠳ㷕႞᷵Ҥ␀㹽㸤✁㤻å᳀෨ࣈԑʉኯ㘿ᔁ㵈❌㳸̣ṐÝ7⥔Ⅴ⡤ᑦၳ΃YἉ㕥㰕㬰ޗ∞రࢸŁ㩶ᷟຄ㕠⑈㭀ᄏ㑐Ġ㏷὜ᑽ㤱ᔥᒊഀ₝໘┘ࢉႱ␇™ᵈޢ៤ᴈ⇹ပ㰰㧦㴑㌙☃Ẏስ᧕▊ᱹ㔣ⴐὑ┥▖ဈ⧃ȕᅰਙ≞὚ᄃ׶⑙㲁⒈ऽӁᙐ㌽㄀㝄ᒉആ⒢֢Ⓡ㜍ᆊᗈِ㈥╥᳌ාऔཱུለ㓈ࡐ⦢ஃ᝼⇘ܡ߈ࣕ㶠┕㱼㧇ᒐĀ⦄ֈ᰽!ᔝᔩǇ࢙୵㏥᜴⒢ࠧړᕧ㴽ࡶดƈ␀㟀ኢ͐ὔ।ᐇ㸱ȉ㔙ẉ㡝ႉ⠠Ӎᰵၨ⧦ሌṑሳ⃾ὰ㧤ॗḥٓ⤧၃࣓㜵ཱ㔳㍒᝖Ȟ⁔ㅥ㠃඗˟᷐ɝ㲂าʥϷጎᵇሟ㢉ᙑめᐰཱུ⌒◒㝽ƒ⒀Ѥ㒂༶੕㔜ᶎ਩㦍܉ს㴡ᒗṍ㍈⟐ᒣ᷶ऐࡄ।̂ᗑḓ௞ᔥࠍ⦌Ҁ㶤ᒼᵖሃ#ᒈࠨည൉ᄁ἟ᵵᴣ\⩃ៈԔჀ㈅┕∳₠᜙ᴨʂℚ¸๛Еვ㑷Б―㧇Հ⣔৵а੹ᠳ๐ൈᕚ✥}㇟ᾑ᱑‰ࢊ♕̃㎐הℂ⑝១㔈ނ၀㨭ЊJὴ዗ᥟภʍᰈ᠅ⵜᴧͣ༮㣼߄ٞ➰㆐ʍ♰ビἀᩊҌ̭ᥳᴇᰂኰ㗓㌡ᄥ£‐ፔ⌌㵾∣ف㹹ᇓࠖ፥औఊၰᑤ㍅བྷ*ធ᡽ᓧ❐፶⥿ґแᇤຕ᥂×ᓒɉȓᒋ㝔ʷᗒၑޥեቔធŷቕर㒀ᙌԃ↑㫉ओ‰ት̷ᯐ՝Ⓩ▅ၑᜍ⊐ᕙœထᄅὕቅ͵ẓ㖕ƒᠫ➕ཱུᐝ␕྇⥥৒ὒೃ㤕゙इᢑḊቴ⟖ᄩᴷᗙ፽ᓅ╌⊑⥥ጂᄠԨᖆᕀ῅႞ᕾᓗ⌷㕗㡄ᙕ≏ᕙ݉἗㧠ᡸוᘹ՞ഡᔔ㐖៥ݽ၁ၥ㒀ᾪㅘ㤟ᓁ㒆ᙗↅᑑ㑼Ôᷡ㗓ௗၘᠥ㑱㝒´ӎȌ㛁㒂ᅵǷᓃ㚕ᇙސἽùᗠढżםၝㄡ᧞Ὅࡔᓜᰵ㬳ॶणᔀ㊁i৊ඖᒆ㗄㝒සǵ⡨ᥒᗄΟ᠃ेÈᙦᦅᝐ┲ʜ㎐ႉõⅺᅁ㔓ᕜὀ᠁㜌ؙ㠁⎶ᵒሶ๑㝠⤒ᵉౣ㡓ᶜᵽㄷ⼍ḵ᜞ᒵĭᖆɕ˒⁼&"፞ɸョɞÁ㝩ጠᶔᤥᑖู⾃㵝᱘㇓౵㗁㙐טↁ✡వ৻ӗ၂ᄞᢤႀ㗀ࡲભ㊗㞗ᅲᴷ⻘ᅁ㮏ᎀ͢ȗ╱߂㔃ա㘗ᧂɋ Ҵ㞞ဃĉንთࡷₒጠ㗔ݝȈ̓≐㽽ᐐៗ΍ၐൈ◝ᩕᵹ㤕ᤕĈ⧖ݡ㙀℧ॖͰؓㄠ㹅ㇷ㝢᭲ӡ⒌ቝᗤࠈṱᗈ⇵Ꭳⷷ㓔ቁ㈃◪ׅ㧣ᡂ̰㟵᝭㩽ឧ㢱Ԯࠤߜ╗⅙ናൕ෣័↝ሢↀॄ㍈✥Ḉᣥ㝕㹹ぴ⁕ေ㥧㐺നᅵܒ⁴Ⓝ㖝ṑ〵ዪᲈⵇṡ㱾ᤔᘅᩂ੊ᜏᙵ೟ႂᕱ᧍৓㢾ॷÆహ㷕㝆ቍ㴱㽉ႁㅅࣆᔨ㳕᧟ᴱ㧐Չቁݔ⊉Š⤗㞕㲄ᣡ⑍๽㴗᎑ⴴࡺឤ⑕ܽᓃ๕㷁ࣘᴵ㩔ҕख┝Ⅲᴦᵐ⊍ᒘᙒ⟝ᑙ㔕ॴ◈ᕆᒐᱵᥕᎈᅣ἟ᑵ∩ᓒ╧ㄈץѡᝅᨠต⑟ᙔ㐔⤃ಷ፥ၽ㕩ᓒᕰョ⹷⊕ᝐЌǑ␍ồᱷ⑒♒㠑ıॎᥑč࠴ᕍ㳠ἒɎሳΞ᝝↛‾ᦁ㉘㐦ཙ㇖ᔨਨ ③☹㕞೟ᕌⅪٽ×࿗ᇴ⃐◟ሉ࢔௙៥㇋ፔ❨ಇᱧ⊙トṐ⩁ᇃՉⅭͤؐᖗ㒏⟐ᵠ☿ᑟ࡙ހםृ┏ᜒກ⤌⊐㑃ᗖ㡘਼⌥ᖍ㔹ᵈߖਙ㷕ਇṇྨբᅃ㵡ᩐ὘ᷴ㝟ᕂӅܧᶙᕵࡸ⡇げ₟ൡ㧸⌥ఽɕߊᕵ㈾Ž࠸㧴⼢Ʌࣔݕ๟ᝋ➝ᄁ㳈㷵ᦁⱔ⢂᥁㉔੝㹇͈Ԝ੤ࢃਝᲄ⓲♖Ṡৰឭᔱݷ▅0ᒞᇁ㲴⡅㽍㥑ጌᰕࢥ᜝ᵌ⁹⏝ቖ‷⍰̈؏㒈⢟ᝒᢁᗉᢕፕඣദǶᗖᕕᴜzᕒ╞ᇽԗ⑶ṕ㠜ᵝ‡·⅙❗ᕝኖ᥺৓┕၇㙄ẞ፟㜞㑑㈟ោ὜ቍᝧ㕐㤀㉷ᑴḘ㧓ᵉƥܣ⃂᷑㇇㞓㌷ἢᑰᶗ࢛ᔐ൑ᇴޕౠ㨕⡷㹥Й❒ᙂባ㝍ሉ㘝ᕾ⌽וᑷᵳᅺ⑕▄৴҉ᣝОፔ᝖ᓹ՗ቝ቗㩥᝔☊㤥ጧগ㝔᱒ᓕ⒈㳕ౄᰖࣼ⒚⊠ぎӇ⥠ংԁᵿᵽ㸂◑‴㨧ሶဇᣇ့∘㓙ቦൗ₂ᣍఘᡤŷ㹠ᷚൈ⁲֙᎐౉ৃ⥜㕢ቖᵗ╨ḿṴ㈐࠹ᝰ〞ἠ⏸੒Αຘ㍔㖩ᨘᇣ╞ቹ⃃├㣹㗤ߜᙰ㗖᐀㗃ͥᰝ㹀ᧁᜫᱸ㨞ː㗰̟✘็઀ᴐࣹ౧༠㏸Ôⓞᇣࠞᕢᇥ఍ἐᱸ☈ࡑ₁㠳ߗᵪᜈ၊᥈ࣣ⠉ǵ㘒⌤ႈᄀҷᱽࠡᒔḘ㡝㼁⠣㗓ތፀזɓᰅടࠖੁᓡ㺙ᅴࣥჾ⁙㧘ňぁ㎔㚝ḤⲌᶗṺ㴤∂Ṟেࠞ㔹ቈࢂü㴽ᝉḧᑫՈ㱗Ⓟ⩃෇ゟቆᄣɼ਩ᴽᝒಈ⤃㚐සᅑ॑ြᐈੀጽߒ៓ᔹ㨣ዙ࠹㴇₌෩㨅₝ԙᙷ╞ᴱ㧤Δ‱ᆓⓟ㼠⠘␗ᵃݝ㒈≽৶ཱྀȵࢯΠᇱ⃁⥟ὸ᭵㙴➭Ẉጘᨁ⤃ㅗᲔôഝࠄ⤠◞ၲ⧟㕒ीȣ᧒⶞㴝㰏ᑾᴵ㜘মエṘ㘹㇢Ƶᔂ㽗⽴෣⫙ራỸ⏢ፉ㇛ᄣ㹕㈙ࠜဴ㧵ថ֤$חᮖ⃀༬౲Ő᜖ᒕ㓔ೈ≖ᤉਈᰰࠕЕृㅶ⎝Ṁ⇉ᥐ㕌Ӌ㜡㴨ℑ⋘୥ँࢁ㸲⛙ޕϡᗇϐᝲࡐ́ॶࡈחᱱㅅ᠐ò὇՝ం⣄ᅋⴒ㨉Ꮬ୴⺃╵㒁᧜ẇⰇ⟑ᵽ㒜⅌ၠ㆘ߐ⟑ㅛ㜕℠ਮ⏓ἵ⧗጖ᑑᡝၺᄔੜ⣾ᔉ㣍∝Ᲊ㉐›ᒅͿյ㉘⼌㏔™ᜫᑕE㼘㈒⊠םႝះࣇⅧⅷ‥ၵᑙ⒍㖨⤠㕟ਤ㜰Eᵱ㷖⅝൘ৱਥ⌳⓷ᝈၣ㇐ै᎙ಔ㕐㰔◝ޞᲩ㤞ஞᙽƑቌီभ㥖ഹ㢔␠ᵹᖀ❠ઽŔࠌ░㉗❶ჽᙔ༏͙㗁ဈ▖ᗦ༟ၹ㤘㬔ᲒᆵЙਈݷѣࠤ⑗፜൵ㄍड़ᝒㇷ㧑ၹʃᡭ₂ⓈƎὕ⡔Ї㽃㤲ᔔ᱘ܼܵᠱ㢕ᮄሀⴇᡪቄঀᰙბ㨔㞀が㦸⭎ὶᤙ㓒ᇊĲ൘᠀ᑜƁ຺ळ㎒ᴴװ⃠֑㷵㸠⇔'ᔓᱴ《☩ᇽ῅ڐݱ೨Ẑ⇥ఔᾦॵ◦㠈ላᵴ㥶ࢭᙄㅎၳᷦͅ㍰ߘᷟ⽘⑇ᐊོ੡⏌Ẉ৥ސ፵ᔈᗘ๶௨ݐḥᑤ✟ႀ׫дᶮŒȣ॑㍶ᤓL㇗ࢌ╷ǍᔮїⴂզǇҙ✬ṵ㝵᠓≑㡦ϙ෹ฐథი㖕Ԙ㕔ᶜ฀ᵼ✲Ქः㊘ᰕṦȒǤ㔂࿜᱑㝊ᚔ⨱⡠ど࿺㹵ᝌ᱆㐀⌟ሥܗ˵ⷙᓤጞᒨ┤Țၣ㍇✝╡ᝉሄℌΒܜ㔈㲈ᵌ⇑᧔Ṓၱȥ⃴៰⧍ᔜ㹇ሢ⸒ඔ⏧៾᝵╸ֈ㉘ᐱ㟞ងⴲⅥݝy㔬⡶Ѡↈန㙝❐᫑㕸ޚཝ㇘⌝㉠╉Ꮟᇎᅅ㐆ࡀ⢨ᓕᨗᷤ߈ൕ㵑Ѐም㗴㬐ᵉ㉔ށḈ᷉㲀ṽㅈᕎႊᴧÉ⃥ᗣ⌂㦀㤧༲Հ❥ߑṉ㒷͹㙲ುሙᘟプ㐊ጨ⢔ીᑶᔧ㔛ᴉ㐍ࠄ㳍ࢥᰀ㷉ߜṵ㕊㏒ȉሁဝάᅗṲء࣐ẅ͸⤢፺࠳≇ᓁቾᑊ₉⁆ᣇൖᎁ㗠Ԙõ㴞4ᙈ⚏㊊Ὁ㴌㘕ṅ㺓♤⒩᧦㡍㑈㥹☞⹵㇢ᇜヸᐁպᄱt㓁ᄩ㢷⛝ೝᗄŠශᠡገ㑶ᕴ❀ḗ⧌Ⲏౄ㗙᜜Řߨ—᱗෗᠞⌔ⷤฤ᷒׻ઞ᠔⧢⋢פए㢉నぅ᠖ෝಔᰂᄽ⣈ᵩ⼉ᶾ㗚Ṱח࢝㍹៕ܐქâЌ‘㦁㥐Ǖᄏ㝑⋡㇕↞łྡྷOⷴುᩒୂ⧥㳀๶ᔕ⊔ၘ⌇❎☃՟㉊ɠৗֆࣾᣁܤᶄᘦ¢ᰈ㦉◐ᴂ౔ݞᅊೠ͏℥Ḑᶜጲ╇࠵㠕࠶ᜁᨭ༇ᾂᔠ㧀݂༦ᔃדჴا㵈ᩈ⏢⒈⦍㗈␅ ヵᇝᲄ⧸ነ㲇੄ド↙ܟ㕐ǁᆃᐟᒩȝᑢ⮰ヤ჈ᴭ㡼៥ⱶ㏽㘞ቌョ្⁔⥒๏ᕙࣷᐩ൹㒤⏔ᵱࢤВౕᨳᓞဨ⮧㌘Հ⊘኉ᇒòᚗぴ㞴ေᴠݐ㜢ीƙ✣පᗙᇾࡾᗍᲆᇃᅗᰁ༩㎸⧗ᤝㄲ㞢ޕᨧ▌≑㩵㸘ᙅ㱗ԭ⑁⭔ᱜᵠⁿ㕒ག⒀㠨ᱧᅶͨὁ㢇᎓᝱㠘Დ㝤㧚ଷ╵ηᜧ㉅う⑁ά゜౐ỹᴰམࢇ㗔ΞԔ㣈Ū൥⋈័⩀㤔ෝ੠㧇ጇブᇇ∺ᝍ㈃┐İけᤖᑺࢅ✠ֈㇷᇩ՟Ÿݬ጑⧤֡ᵝ౗࢓෤ᤊᐥ㩽᷇㟣ᗑ㐄Ȟ֢ࢣ╜ဍ㥗ᐕ ᒡᕤᒙ㈶⇜㙡㰂͍㘱Ӆ݊ः᧤ⷑȭḅᏟṶᴲ؞ၳሱᴙⱹᄈᱱ☹㹔㥷㵒ᜒᑂ♼࢕ሌ▌㕌w㥔ݝC㲉ᜟࠣ㷃ኍᙆԄ࢝ᒈ×ߝᱴそᜀဈࡒ❐ᴸᗎᗾხȔʍਲ਼㜀በၗ㷟࡞ṁড়᧼⒀ೇ⚎ࡄᤤ៝᝙ܧࡎ⃀⠧±᝸⢘❥ᕱ㴳ᜟᠴ㉑ᓀậǷᙑሰ㴷ᐏᔠ⡧Ꮪ†㤶ᐟඈᐗ㌎ⴀࢍ᠔ᑃ×ߝᶠ⁒✂ᒕঌ㓀ᔠごʣ㍠߀᜕┰ᓤἜօソЅాᇩᬈᆵᇳՓᡍ⍓㟕ࡤ✗㉎ိᔏƊᕰᓃՑᩇ㈴⍐‘ᘐ⌞㠈㵡␷ᷝ᧔᜕ԥ㇅᝜Ąj̕ٴ㕤ཝ‷गऒఅᡔṗ㝀ㇺ݌ȕአňٍ⃭㸊㽵㤞␙ᒀހべ԰ͷ੘Q㷄㞂ԩøၱぶ㠁Ҙঢ়⁅ဢԈᓧኤ၇೔ሕό㵧Џ൸⣴⎝ᔌ⍽Ẓ㽋➗ᬖ౥ǉᝦᱸㅠ╱άᷠ❈ሹā㼙ⅅහᴬ⩃ऀݒ0ǉ␌㽕ᘥࡗ῕҂9๥㳵⭾ᄃУȖេ㧆ᔐ㦇㲉ᮇ㟈㩗ᒐ᷁㭡↜ตᐗ㇐ᑥ㸂⋬ࠄㇵݡ㡸ňᅗ㏁ࠆ⁘㗙ᩅ╅ᲇഁᚩန࿴➝ᇙᐃϘƁㄜᕆᥥഃ㓉ᄅೀࠣ൵դ㜝᥵ȉ°⁵ᵕ◕ᅺशᤶෝၥࠨ゘Ԫ⧡࢐ᙖࢷ㝔ᒩ㈃ᕣژ㕒ւᣲ᝙ን╚ǔ◵⡹҇ᦟ㊁㴤೵᱂⧚ኅၱ㷕՞ᚉ㌍␡Č㹼ᕟ቉ᓅⰲ⣚⒔ᝐႹइᝑံ᷁ᘅᝁㆡᕿᵑኈ ‍἟Ü㖌㕅ⓞぁḥᜄᶙ⎥ᙑ㲥ヰȿၖᓼշᔌќὑᔀᄖტதᐕ෭㆚☿ᕛ㥓ʅ㴱ហᏑႆऽᘂᔥ㥒Ӄᑗধ㜖ᙘ㵼⎟Ṹ㥅ݿᑥ₤㲕ᤔD܀Ἂԣޝಝ㢗ઙ☰ࠍ㒵〚ᘧጀ༆ᆀ▐╌㚂₌م㔱ᚐᅈɝ㪕ὰ㕔஢⌕㡧ᔞែ༌っ₝㗧Ԗᶤᄅ⮆՚॔ුἷᦤ␅q♹ᒐᶑ㣅⅝Ō㷇ͣࠆ㦣㸂ἃקԐᑀᒣܕሾỔ᎗すȆ᜖ჵ㷴ԐᒧᄱᵓベƘʕ᳌ㄕₜƑ⏫㓢੝Ƿᜏᕁᵉᚕ࠘ᇵᨊ≁㷗㔨਒೓ፉᙕゖሞਸ৕㟊ဃᤤսဂw᠕ₖǵႏ∽㖔✶ႀ͖ẕ⠠ᗸ㌡Ṳधޝ⭱⢌≜ㅥ㈔⊇ᙕ㷷ᣝᄈ⣰‒ᙂ⏗❙ᑣ㇔ৢశ⧗⑘ḱₔ⚒៭㕅⒏ᙁ㕖‹Ḿᵐ᏾ᰡ㘈঄᳝㈒⡟ḽѻⓔᣉ⌤֚ᯯ㢴㝎፠ᨘឤ≇ᢗ㞌X㗥ঐ႙רኢUऔ㝒∰֒⍶ᇊ̡⍌ᝈ݈ᗟ᱘ু㣠ᥗខߣᕝࢁါṔৰ᎝ᰠ㈀ࢨవᗢ͠ࠅሀ⊊ŀㅗ㟕ၕᢀᅊ౨᠂⃠㏘ᔗ̙ॖȃᲉḱ㧹ᡠࠑ㷅㩟᱅㧤㌩⅝㢀൐⾥৕ẊᗦࣇqṠሥ➉㔻㴠ᢖὟ੗㞏Ṹᒀኅṇ‟┓㕁㴗㍒ࣁ㖙ܰ⠀᜗⠨Ձ෤០Š㉢ᖖ∸෢ៀॠ㇟ᠨx⃥ဢ㥵‚ᓦ⁕㷠ᖃᵔǄᩖ୥㈃᜾᰷‗ӵㆈ㸲ᘃᗣࡇᲘࠔԳ➌ƌ㥧␙ṹऀᶌ㝴◲ƀ̵ㅕ㟀㾑↔ᶥ⩣ᣢ☟ᴶᙞݲᑶ⧢̀ゖࠧ⚞⅝⇇『࢕⦷ϝ╵᠇㢈⟕㐢ðᕑアaቈ㈈⅝㙽ɷݝļטࠢ൑ㆥḊᰔ㉡ᠼ㳔㄁Րちࡢ⌝᱔㷈ᦟ⅁㥣ᝀⅠÀᜫ⦁㏗⠰ᔁてᡬᦠ゗〴᳣ᄐǺߒվᏕᄹ㹜ឡഇ㜠ᑹឝܨ㗧፝☏㧗ᙝ㱩㧠ձニজ㨷☃㍠ԡሡ°┟յᇌ٘ ɴड़ฏᰆχ⒚ᘱᗖ㮒ḋҬሎ☦⥛ㇹᅵ㻗≙ṵᖌ㮖 Ъ᠀㌟ₓ≦⃽㖉᝗ₗ❝ᵝȵቢ੕㦵㧧㩜ຩᖙٔṔ㙉᥸㍄ɗჁćྕ㹗⟀ẵ⠀⨔╇ޠ⑕╹㸒ၝዉב੒ķ႖ᘅ㘔▏᱾ࠠ㚑ᙰ⇉਱ώᄧ㰙㳐̧ᵴᒈ㔥≘㉅ਹ㒘ঁ᳒ಉ㷗ȝኖᘙࠐŵ㇎✌ࡶ‖ࢁⲽᡫ㍝ၨ㐟ʁᑱガⲲ቎㞥ᴎ࠹㇍ଉᇒᡛᖼೈ㴭၍၎㒖ᕙṖ㟑᥹ൈⓨᩒụⱝ㞴➞ėᐭ㍥㐂▕ᒵቦ㝐gťⓍᩱ▟ᤂゐёԵᖝែᔅᓨᾌᚂ㴤ᒭᰳ─๩ᰠἊፁབ⑚ᒇㅝ▒Ş⑺ȼӵᗑДുᖦᾝᇺഉᓥ㕝㥹㧕ࣁ_ث㟁Ṇ㠟◙ᴾ᜝㹣⒖ץ╣৕㮴⻖⇟ᡘڌɂ֖ᠭ㨦⇸⑙㊌⮖ጃᰦ㐛㎝ㆥⷲٛᅹ㲊ُ஝㈘༩㩀〘❞መⰮᖔᒀ៳▸㭴㣷এᕹ㡈㛤⏅㸉Ѕˆ㊅⣓⍲ė╹ᴣნ₌ᵘᦵ㉖དྷᄸ㌑ቁᅇ༥ᐍᚅἆ᜔ↄʘၐTᤍ≂᳁E★౰㎂⁼ㅱာࡰŅ╙ᾉㄈ⛤◜㥑≊̷ᵌ㴠⍉ᔀゥ㦖Ἀዏ㠖ਕ↦᎜ႀᗢᲗ╎ঁផṝ⧋㭀ࢶᆍዞ⌘㕢␉㖆ಃ།ᠰ╉⚁ᕥח⾁෕Тᗥ∦0ಌܗɖԅ㉙շ╔㩖ṅ⥵ᐔṑᆕὙ≜ৠㆄ܂ᝢ㩀Ⱑ〕◕᥏Ɔࠧ᎞բ⃁㓕ࣘᴦȘ਑㓗ܪ㝩։ᤖဟᄔ㍏์c⊕Ű᝻Ἔ㹽ᤁ⊡ᣒۄᯐᑈ㕩㕊ᕈԅ㨼ੀ៴㙝෭ᵭᤜಕᓍ؜⵭㗕ጕ←ଈɀݧПઠƎ〞મԭ៟ઘㅠ⟣ႣǳˣΏⱠȋᯪ⃵አ၉㭥㵢⹦ংߠ㰲━᪛༠㻖⁐⊁ึ⌜⠅㹉ૃ๊ರᛟὲ㴀ᰌᦍ⠱㴕⒒⓰⟺హ㲖⤟ṂË㡡ߵ㠧࿎◁ࢠ̘ⅾસڞႁ㧠᭹ࠥ⦃もרù᤮ిำ㯣ᠺᥦ㖦حමࣖ́ᠦ⏣⍏㰥⚞ጇ㧸߯ᱹ㦗╹㧥㈱ᰨ㥳฀ᶟှ₂ȏ⠉㘤ఆṹ㏥␰㩯 㒞≀㡈݂࠹ᛸ㋟ᨰ‪πᕿ㊏Ɂ⌠㰧Ԡ࡟⮀ឈպ⨻▎㖖㰝⻡ᾇヘ⊖㼋὜⤢ེ؁Ἔ‱⠅᠌ᠶ՞ᰐ㡅㋡ࠂ֨⠣ຐòాᱰঃ⥊㣌⌌ȸɷখ᚞ḱះզ†គơ㎍㧉ₘ㺐ই⌨∏⌟㤑µᛥᚵዄᄶብ㞌܅⛐⒄㢃ጝൂᔆᢄ㠙ᐘ㝴ࡓ㳲ᜃຊࡕ⊳㨮㳒ㆳᴣᰠṏ㌹㩄Ἄ㪐᷐Łᔴ㞑⪇᱕Ĺ᥏జ """
l=""
for i in range(16385):l+=chr(i)
a="0123"
z=dict(zip(l,(q+w+e+r+t+y+u for q in a for w in a for e in a for r in a for t in a for y in a for u in a)))
c=""
for i in range(4268):c+=z[b[i]]
print(c+"0"*27)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZrdj@Nodt4vAsTGIkAQIEByE3gyjpMdTwysvY6/gAUCJM6FESAIYAMxHMNZj531BMbau1hjswsEISVRJFWURFKkKFWLEimRolTdVa0PUpTUUjXQ1dVd1ds909NT1T2zrup@zzl/yOZwbvYmNw11t0Txfc85z/P8Xupvf/SDv/qb737zZz/75fd@7Vd/7b2P/uYvPv7ud37vvT/6w//0a79T/MvX/vxb77///lWZ3ArGR2JfehRgEMO9LnqtLzPsSjiLQapCPkB/CPcTVGORD2G4JksGuQSyDauMtB0e1C@P0Yqx38S@g/s2HebQb@A8xIYG0R7uHNI@F3clSg3YLTFeYZJBcI8kDQ8OL0fgTcm1xf4OLnK8Y9Mght0C7g7Ebo9Oh5pD6mgQS6Su0Rugk1LZ@8eYeTguQU@jI4v8DgQHcGdO4xn2axDuUXVg36MkpVEJ7jVRGcHBiloDWGro5TD1cRrS4MEfiHwDtbXYdyE@fn5Apil2G8q3nzt4uqWqKVYKLBx6cCA2A9TnGKvPXQhmlzsxNEXYEHkO9l2Yjd/mYmPi7iGFGt6JYDW/0CEZ4HROmxp2e9RXzmrQbYjjDaVlbKuoe3C3dLlDVyEtEsuHkNqw2VJPg2VIkodeigczzJJvojWDvoE1F2bKn6E0u16Iaefd7nZy7oFyiI4MExOCBShcuYfQk0gqo6dSbNHeeD1HP4JJRsdDlHpvSyj5NG1fjm/q1OuAvycpRnVNB6ekeGA2UO@T7NJgCEsZetHzJmx1EefkxOIoeJqAb55bsBqh2kG5Q@UW1XoU1tG7@3gC8gySDcxKqMSYNmlwB3WFph41E8jbEKsw8DAsvcgx8iibYB7RiYmVPaS1V03IMlqWqX1P7OOnmph2YVbBQ@n5TKxKX1TAH8DCfeTcGFTdXrlwWgW3S/EEy31wc5ISmDXBm0OljEogAoU8GZMByO6Zg1Lzd/8B9ROSFcpLYlZ9nIjVGJz@9RpG3Kl3IEtxHoA7xhMdPQn7nT@mfg6uRuUtRSbKupjvrocibYvEwI731iK1LcLk@hT00pMW@DJt7asRDXzIRtCLcZ1TpF90gfcws0gqQVDDVUzKKfQMKruflsk3yI3F8oC83Xn2hzAuob@BXAL/PuyCNx1M@mezq6ZY@jDSoOuIjf/vwR2gm8NmAVEHrAHsNo@cT2KSHcolVHw8GELQJCVFowy582QkZjORbEEPaRqdHaFknFeh2xIPjYsYJ6MX2cWS5wfi2eWeFPuZImYBRhH1GpDNaBzCfgDahNwUzPvEhevf@R9ioZFUF0kf4zVGFZjvL0qPpzDUUTqlfIgliTIdvPxmCHmFyv1PHSxzi1VgyF0bkyrRvAdSio4qZjl2t1DhzdJxz9ts3mS49Ymn2ujDqvIrsK6JtEssLHZNJKdvFDB6NKi/i7ASoeOSWsdBj1wJBjFqFlk@xF1xdCjmS1LL3LFzn8rl5xksJxCMH/fI2oukfONgsH/EmqLAfiviBPtdCKb8RrE2xGwO@9ZND@oBci8NOiJY0DoXu4ALIKIIOqXzjJrtZ52r5btScVdZhkYEvTrJdXB4OtxfEYl2W0FFejoSoU@zGUWS2EtiotGA56ovtjK5NTA12O0o97DZ4LH9NEIzgK2KZe9JD@b25/z3gZjEZwMacGNlYD4gLYB480inbgeyFW2DWxOlPZU16OgQl0Ue30jgytg4eNEVXJnQgmoD9gpXAntHUAkhNqnuQToXSZuGEqxsaCUQcy1k7Koi0CHriI0LO5m4XlLjRU8E5b9PxPwQJO4RR2wVqOgkpc/aIpuhMbswYF7@5594RaeUHSyVIJmRFIlsitrs0gfdAWVxpVLQhXBCSoLDLmR10jwRDqHtPC@/PfysQoP81odgSbkLpT7k2SteukSbPa0j7MkUPTiLYSmJfCJG2pX1TIfafeo8BEemTEOen@X6@Qg25pn/2xg7qEQYRmCNQV5@Uv5j2Ok8XzRz6d7srYdavxiG4fpcpumKbeyRKbYVcgO0NDqWoNIky3wcUDNnswBrT9EcnLgociphyRcPOmw/YqhDaY6m@ogXo70dwiCCVEN1A5JbFDsZU2qR0cVOGbYN0DJIXGzXYL4hZ4SpCXsLnRjbbWC3S8oXLigzMemy2sL@kGXrzQqtLi1ktLnf9p/L0DXJ2FNFIr8Cti7SKtrD10NsqdSrQ7UGnvalSVqMLm@TIfKmiByxz0DTqKWJ0MTxUJyUwd@xUN@E7zQxcmkVFMMz31Gigm0@lnBcea3BbP8vwfHBmT5VxbArjrnPY@il/HUiSH7aAjehdC/ClVg7T7SiRgMJasMXvCJHxBGYKq3Z6MjpslFQ6ENJxyD4vA6zDOQJJmPQDNhYoC2xfAp73qlIxB6s4y9bGCUgl8WoRb1M7OfkLB/JVLfBb1/0kYVNiSkoi5X3kwHk5qVPi5JYL57Fn@ZgsEypoA2Iq9K1qCSDOePVo2GjZ5O/f1RGW/osIrskdisxdcnpwaohJlMa1290KIeUhmB7sKlTXcOBCfYI8pWI2M4rvKjnJfAsWLfE/T53ggjqODZeSbSKwN5B1gat/MvAdQomILES6FCRYTdgA4N09N9xWoaBduVAWSJN4Q1HXnkpgF4X0smzElYOH63F5s5LF8ouWflLC7mBEvVawpEjkuzlTEw3PBecJESmgXuIvfj/kDqAUwvm1iNdDDlKuM/L1DDfOFgpIYvfICRHe8tBTKLJ8cvaH8A@hQPW9oFYB8@4EBoECmY9SJMXI7E7odHuXeXLPvZnnG2e1bHLY9yCnQTT2ivj@THES0hVdnGozchrkRFCJX40QsmEuvNP0TAoO0Vt9KVMmw2oLRG0oR4X3TerFQHAiqiuiL33q9C3OYKx1qDPn1xh/PCVJTYyqJHYuhCXzjxo2Zf6RQvsA/KdZzl4NsjW2/g6LiSkb5/noLsimpEtQde4KmPVoru6iFocgEDPnudw37z2sdXEtsIfZDHGmsmx4BFLmwUVlnkXdOVFBtsWtd0nNgR3se8WQ2L6aLriVMU4FokNe1tw8ohcKnVFpMKQS18DPcVBGypTSPnGulDnlSjocgaz@FNglKASXE2gzTlEgodKoWHuKbQ8NHJyPQor0HVRb/Lt3Oqw8ygJIFy/caGzue4Lbj7HIbPN/nW7B5lTdFws8vSIlA5FA2jJZLNbe1hVwGJ/2505kIdcDHHfA5lTbkzWnHz7Ufp548KgO/z2EijZ0xxaZTp0Qe2@NWG3P9uAF4hoeL5744PsE3tBwnJTF6EDrR4PKN1bipjbfgSORDX5Y5HUxKoNdpW8Cl9e5OWnGYYTiG3wKp8MgKcxVs84kYxhrHASRGfxrMedyDN/lqGyBUUmhxWjB3sJApl6xhddCtibVpDZoK3EhkM65wwbMs5UIwpbsOpBxjKX464O6@xfQK8Pdvb4mDf20v2JjfLuX78P9f7lmsrJZf9MJn8KRgArB6IYrLZYb/C0TJkP8w6pLRb2ecbRj7omh6iqjL1QzDKRPPjcK0Cl0odhBJxTPEmEC3F0TDWP@pygF1xkfNApbv@kCQ3pxfDCQ3f@rkRO@TqkjgdJ6fLgvVcp9fsglR@zGfH4sp/lWLL5fshzbv0L7XkLdZP2@38GpslR95M6yMUQo@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@3J954qEHaoplk@EYNPYJR9xnBOHgfcC6jf5ELFSYJ1jrFtmROXXKUly@1lE5fhF9YULbI7tZWGEWIOcsayDC7lvpjS/iMjpN6NkcYDFi/TPJKoPXprAjJjs0YmjXydlwKHrX5kDDBRYTbgxVnE6uh6DwcIYw5bDQgTwlpji39Llyk8CqC24mQs6rKud8LA1EFlKy5uuJ2f7SfVfj/ybt9FFDBGsGeNwNL7lPnFuXGRz8A@z77Lq01CjPeKNw7uCwBDHvmCOmPm3UF9pVT0wjMSyLiQ@LCrYW2G3DJhAJo/QxOPPbnH3jG2D3fwlUmRYphgrt68zMYBgwc8WQUxATnYHyBpucatso5VifPde@aJKt4ZBvw4ahDJ5eEE7dFauRSMdPV7w34LqQ9n4MLndPH9T9lYfWCrg9A1Y7H6XwE5XHEn0PXB9qTMZbnhKOCiCr1K3Atg/1AfX6xNqvDWBQKXKpXgc/IddkrCA9ByuFdYeSFivpk/hmhOUS5MylKvXZsXPYDcGawcoTwzvgsAhZ3BtvXTEPaOJimNMmfsnfb0O3BPqI/Dp3DHV8tjA09uxSVg7ZEpQtjxa2KyJJX@kw8l/yfTmczqC1ufYKedI9msbgO9ipEeuxkYixx1bOIAMtl5Msj7SYV2DWFqMd2odYC0hufM62G4hx6UqG7GEh/usSepyCUpok7BEgqTBSgfda61CrC/pYZF4BGaO6mHUgjM757gPIDwtllRevu9Bg1dcZ8DDu/QK5Q64U8CfcCawfwiYlzRTBBnxGlD7DNTbXYmp/Yolth@oOtacw6YA6Kuqkb7DMvd6j0YY8Fk/gYMS15MTrlV/EMOO2kiCRoXcX5mua9H9ikjd7PsAe45MqjiRITTHaiHnC2EjN9ZmDLS7@SAQcDYagcmPXYcc6s8YOJ3QLWfuC5TvGqCPoaSDXIOaUPsJAf5pRxy7wsqRBRXqVM2qLgPOqU5Sc2XInYzDiNPDWgLr0pn3Zgpki0gEnMcFD3Qpp2wUlFaMYyqcodynpnGsky9Rw6NAH5quFwa1RnDSlEWol2PRFwiDYL8ZY18SwdLbjyA@@DusErLvXGs29/4scf6aMmyqVBqBXmd4vdxyooXijLdgOIo4eJkcGUCzBQyTtmHXFVAJj/84GpllnQ5MRHHS5GpSqWGJomdJEYcK66kI3LypQaH/0iYPSHKotbA2I6xV00OQ9Kt/6xdTpTPIrcSpfZGJ4/5MA1DmWZYwHsF8Dk0s3RZ7trQZGByZycUuKBwvnLBWpL4IKRgF6fZAXmAyKo8ZYuhhBYuOqTykjexOs08I7uKDjEypNYNMhVlp1@CQDp0R7D/cpuyje7YJ2Fx6ssTmEuk7qHd4M4unWeG3FEQclGfTN19G/euPBSRvLktjdE/PFuQk9DlcuG7hY8lLaEOliwgA2E4H7ks2I73aFDTZZCVW9wHbX@PyAegwrE6xYeNARxxy0ZTGUab3AO9237qcheOqnJvgLRr7nchHmQo2/dT5nW4XAPFvAXr32xayEowooB5jaNNGh2RPHKW7L6Ga/SLYMSa84g5ipOLCKgbR7qBggB1TtvDP530i5Qz0XK4GYnGCTUSHDxAOjzdkUGPjkLVRYdXs4OgVHp1EdNVZcnXQTpS3YyouH19k/YSvDnUFNh/mZB8hyf592HdJs1gQOpyWGGFWMWBUTVHKU2FAztmi069SecNXIHYhJRL3Z70M2p7yNii@yjkjmYhKjscRWDj6P0IhUU8QaNLpi4RRaOXM4fL3tw2JKUV@c9KG7f2KBboB0IqJjitsi3dDQKQ5hsg20JfQDcbQ/d0RgYNsi3UN/BeV9cQS3a77ocrQs8J0h3hsLzggyR7oO3XNgYUM1e9nlat7mn/HEcybxoN4TWUaVuoh7PCJFuEss/sizMoTHLGjY0p40mFEwdF6qtGcAWTAVcJC9yW52EMyJXeWkApqETGPhEegVMZZg1oWyRROH@hLJBo3XeMwXWUHUJU4fau3xgjcGAgms3hNZbLciWlLDhjR9M8Ny8Npiv6R1gKrzb4CT@jwlqYadKXsUQ8xPzdu5WE5gaxZH/DMHTsciztAbE4dQ7QCylLjBhsfQrZDSAHkJ@fiFQvXZu07xcGDfQUsFsyb2OzENsWnwIIokZhSp8/xo4LFOrsT9ya3J9M@ciD1OidKbuy9TWJ2c2xcjlg2q81Ja/5lUdi4D3fxpHZyTzzxMS9fjp@qrLvbuwSYjP4OAw7ZF4fjTrsg3Ym2KGctdh0HvqvNIJtdhshBrCbId9haw4LkpU63Dvg6b8YX9NCKnJB72GKnJr8Ghg5M5huxOU/FwSxuO0gbMq2RKaHCYim@8n2SYd6EVgcF8MkEnujgs2q2uYs9HNyy0UqtgxfjEvukxjNNCK5KDakHiwIaxdn4RYzmFwQwTXlGPA0qRwte2WDnYTGBwCn6G7vq1xnMC5pwGfehXMF2gEt/6PyLnHoarzwKsaiA51PULpL5rkbt@eyj2PqkdNHzSA3R5tpugNkBRyKyKUMLhhK0YJh7k0TuNKYAy66UEmk9eSvc47PGYOm/lggFynRYScLpWOBE3oFSDNDnTsRyDN0KjRGOJIra2xTVPSfzOgo1Odv5iQ92FWMqgdaEzoLJHZg2MCXL6vMs9uAInIecOpPovkslpt0LLehGsZhLlOjssl9KtUdO@4O3j0fJhPwdW7M3ii1CMTNgqL9YYschuRbBEXWUwBv0UrBqWdJSrnBNE1oaGTF5w1TnLKO3/JnQ1PGxSrQZ7nVKDOlxwhbYt7EZoTyEZU1gnS6N4g50@8verbM09Kq/BlK9ZyOY/IP6SypSGOd7xixN4r3IeiFwGdmBDI16Sm6IvwdrDxMBFgwMOeaxpvfPOO47nPMCeyD0I@mg4mEdiHUFuv3kgjvoQOJgM8WD4JhJRk4a6mE1IZplui9xnwSqOXCp7HHHrTHGnw@qUvEPYzN7wLPhU38DAvTGhHJ8NXxoodYj5IDafusX5pc/uEJLqYrV/XhKnw/@CeVpUZWqL4xImMS0lnj1wXKw5IHO3qOg3sFO@HpBeu@RM7L2uCpbvkXwTwaoCnfGjIcw0GuvomZCWxNy57YNSE8vgRRMrzIxmQe7GAl0ODhkFrghW0JNhcix2KpyWwAkokW5LYjcGp/ymBeX0i4QyDaYauyZHQxzXiaHWVFDSqZyB@lVIT9bAfLFQxbRCZR2r3Rv2afOpDNUymAOwpxdMbkM8YciKgDEmPaZwVzwFmK@ouacOhziD@QsGjKwOxrbYFCcwYpSDORUM4HaETYctRAyjl7aY82AsgUOaNMGThIwOtzZrRE0H1WbnPPQYh6mfMg5DGtya1BtyYnjCGjQSq7Q4FFJPRXgKXh0WVWaponNnsthNqbEuDDLyqbKg/vAtf02CbaPQqymrLyOowonq6hgtGY@5YXoFc8kPv3r4WUJbomDCpAbK6sUE9jINVWi0wJ9T0IFFi/yIkkNxjwNT9kkOvYR0heQqX4uHh0o9MTfhwQbSmdh3xFAlz/mkf@XQSDs/ElmMB1pxCDDlWXaKrpsGxWGwoVK5DaqK2hb8enG04JiPZyRbELHJb8VQwV7A2qTmoE6vB@fr23tgWJhEr0PmGcEdP2yJPIKoBmZcnEFwShyMwLPIrFz0Xw/FkAM2JyOmKw9M9z2wQ3AjsLukrZCnrxvSrPSiTp3558ptjaUakghz6@IY1go0B8Ctmy6@6BeOo3EtujjfQEXjlFOA8MahOKfMfsTJ3AarhN2dYOvU2MENTlA/pNi59f8DLXTocUQeESfUWh261asKjxXY2pn3zi@MUPahJ7G9i9Au5DVdg9cA7xTKJxfOs7qYLIn/Ww9A9ihnOO7DRhYcnBImG0ksVTxsiLACUQQDH/zuTSLCBkc/DJJHc/DXOOywbII7p3TJNwJBSroFLQm2x09z6FqgzSjlNm3y5GCYQPMQpYCiFbe9WGlgemQ0MJXEsM4yAlb5q7tecdvY2CtxqBRjg/hqPHay84yNKXgnAWc2Z1aY1q73WqHS/qUiZqdcQbincVwBdXndgrCO9RYNXBGyH3ukN0BiOG4@Yf7mj5avLZiqpKVYNx9Z0DHR6HMYYKZHM4fcL@yt517FpCrg9x5X/tdz98uU3IhNiWlZRJ6IbDFTIGQXZDKUSN3eGhcu1IJz7cs6lo9pXaN9xuEMzS7Y0lsONZur2YtcTDv/lfIK9UtX07M1@yfJKwrkV5z5fGTNlIZXWvEYqxYxM4ulA5oL@w1lycumyNY4Sosc7RhY38PWpv0B9j241xbz@KkO/rjgN4Xdcl74TR4gZ0dt81imXRcVReQVSO8VrBNJt/Y3nupoGrR3oROL0IOH7qvS74oNK2qGx6dQKb8cXbRhIFNSZdCmsVo02gm3v0ZTrzhWymU6DrHKYcQtqqiaYMUF8h7cK@xQzW5DCtfnGosHNWURVIun6iwtUwVdBVgJUxkOp@z64mFaHHqoXTDLn3aeyFTpFQdXcSzSMrV0qCiCRT4Ycea85qTsQ5xd6I9myEE6c9FzmeYFt1O04rEHORbBhEqdqyNMQjE0odsWw7xAd3vK4w/u6KcdlqPXTN0LbmaouegePuUwnWG4eaXCeEA1melRLDOYs8EcQk0pipS713041Mmooxk@NmizA5dpUS/OzmcLHB0iQywPV2lTHLT7TIkr3qDi9NCXqcqi8BAyC2raeygxKw/OelTMsMIgzfxapMZeBVZdbMTFU59FTOXZxUOQ2/8QWrvrnOv9WQ/2FjgSVNpQHoqTiNVG5MdUPSzOtNw7FLeeKZTOoR9A04JSVUR76LBbxRTbn5fB8sQ4Iaa0boc4OTZYetYUK7cPuWhYimjhQuT8xxsJdrWr0Vs2bZ@GnjjqYocZrk52RtIhdBIwGPmqUJWwbaJr0GGJcfdLhZw5HJqgaJc@HbnFszDXESdDNFziiXf6MGC/NEgeMROTl1y1YRVxXfGken0oYtZrB3Y5jCN2ze9hd1N018qikcI0dG5Qrr5g8qjSeMTtBbvym@SKe00Ce3TDangKDxxosKN1L6oFhpYzylN@g51w5oGsReXuk84zF5YGVVws9Z5Y2LxLraGY@qxPPbZRmcMiHLLRd0DNYFJDXabco@JY0hbLFpMwdF0qtUHri8laJC4NaiCVWRGv9yCVfggBX7f9NINSE7U9tR3srTj/v2jD1sUgAG9dPGraLESUvPXxeI4MAHqveAioOVhTi4vnOYx8Vn4czVAqDq@wyYTWBYvBzxHJUMxWbLxodWA9x5KDhzYMjov@sZvQZShoPzqA9SlkJjRPYRZSRxPjCiz9gkPDAaz3nz3AlgMjHY3o9SHcv0/DlPwG1IPilKgfFRF06FHf@G/kxWLMfdx9M4Ha8I9E5JBvozZ7bSMTjFp7HmLdYCa9ZewZMNOJRKZRAGx/ffndCFyfIR6ku7BxivNI1qpZQBqr@0TMMvCGL4rfsBToV6udS8TSMHBBdmEoFRlsPoGgxDBHzQ443vOuiNsXZQZuXjQlGwj5s4x5Ck35ixVKIjKm3CE0lERm4mnMlYFtrSDYkfo92ATMN9jXyXlAaQDDNuwHYsprbHLrsyIXg71RURqg0yKXZ96jui1GMrW7NzNkzux5GEyu5cL@B8F5QPoQ2m3U1sVPxAaSiIPi4WUw@d8FSEhDirNHJWiNUeZqBtAuQ@Y8rcC0LY7jQnh6XBfmf@/zjKoarRfQKTN@iFCFRUcEztUS@8YTg@Kk8IsNq4gEK4P8FL3FE@l5Rgp3nUSnFlYZAGOcjmA0xM4A0hV0@7cLJhKO4M8lblMRJHjYL345o6okNTgy4Dj/lGGO0VKloYYDl8zh2Qxci0rDb4OukaYV@9jdX@a3/uPdG76hocgsqsbF88KZQ3oIwY6WDlXka5PkUIQ825wtHMo1lkxUOLCPwJdQCc544@4iJ3hu4GBW/KpBHkN4D8YBlTySUliOoGI@3b6zr0@hyRmfc04P@qFIVeoFYG2g799MWCSg7mOnSRw3uz7Np5QE13MqH4hxjyY5J3xOAlchaCE7gTO4ZtM3vuygPLhMRcyW1IRZ9VMVbRateXGmf2LD@uDVPdAYDsYY3yF1A0pGDzzUebszYDU@aaNUfXkEgUTGAEtM4WMs8zizr3pY4nH0ORJeZKAPi@fu44yShKY9sZ1Cu/slxwDGVx3iNdUrlx6U5ceqOHVp4@GAo1DGDYUTh6HibVAcPbsbWjM8@3Cgv7HE1H6cA@tLR6GOg@0mzE9FENChBd0ZqrqYsJ3voZL8As26tDSfJ5ClnO/IiVHvcEoWEwaAjhjLsLTFQmfxuvjq9L3TFYF5ziTYwJ4hwhVKbIYyLvYQ3qU6m@WEzMEzGSyO1/dwsQC9Qf0Y0kZxkqnWxb2CFyC8A@2dWGqUHoNcB7lBdpvZAzZtGlgQb4rj6taEiQweMK74zBXY7z/mOHxM9ZjMErZdsHnbxuSb3zmPsVWH6RzbA4hKVDI/s6549312CHAU4OucGnBYYgcG@xhmS3SY76YsImxMUJfFvo3WIdgqcXu37fM@WtuL3eesLNZLR2QytMdwylliK1K25phcn3mYEpfn@s@@uEsDGTZVCgbIOSQ9hZ5PmxHa7TcxuqNC109SfNBGHuuw81PjsvS6DcExTcaorovfsNQMPGmDUYbZmMw71PB5QDBffHkHlA0tal82xQkLbqfgJMYQiWNxH7QOzk6g7RSCM1hie03HKY1yMWbf2VCo0R0GN4XW@kvlkUY1BUctrC8ee9whkI6g3GN/hawD3G56W@xtqLCZWKDLoKhiF4NZh0MF2JJ7DlYrzzogm38IUR31Eizl38eOIuYzapRQ3pEyB@meCGfnHMC6cKpTpfgxJ3o9ii3Ua89zyAxWSmS7c1hHYhq3YafBQZOY4ydM4GNo9NjXWMVhwTfYKBqu78LGx@SAjlnjV1Ctw0EfDY5YQzR1alfFoix2nOxn6Op4KIMbv/HwlEXVfTkEL0Zt/A2xMG68y/aVQnr3muHPoWkbNgrGGZhO8QObKieKLjumSAKqVm5K4A95g5FtTvoq/8XNJ1UWPWj0r4dYlqnlfvWodHzREROLWt7NEfnT13qBfNIAKg7Vm2JjfIQ193wG/gOGCNrsIZKxFsLI/vsK3Od4oZE7LX7W5mp8Y5Ndcd4/SKnrc@iC7BiinuDI1Kp/0cPsmPgmDN4gU9zTLqXb5OVAHAVPGiT1xdHJ1TEM@O@dIpczOpZGT5c/GcHDBzgPLg7g/hGWM6YGkHVio8iGuBmLceldQJwqHRmO7hTPXLgpZRNrsliv0OhhoNBGF3fLYlMTixncGcB@QakEMwPGdQyYxFy0bWzNcLAtHk0v2hhx4CudHVAYvssoSMTDBnqyGAbPO6iciqP1T/vFE@skgOONCGIcl6lUejM520B0ImYPxXpJ90cQbCEeU3v8xbFYrcWo/VyGYIzNEdabNIvZdAreTtbv7hc/DhsXPUwJm98cZhOKl8Wh5WoA0imWShdNDHTqRGJWZbOjZozmjKb3USqR3Udd4sm4LRVPt@6s6WAAE05FR59KnKKp1ryU0eDtSa4CEQ7wRIK@dr3FyQNsN6jdppmPD0I4ZfDvYK1NuwPY9zAaiv32C5lLjdKc9w8CA4IVR/qZSaFCB6EISq8nyJCxNc8W/6igyflMjMsY12hkoGFcrC95aNvAa1zPYaBej5lioV96ElKjTomOpQ5tTTFW0Zig1kRjQJH1KIM7MRxmcFCBygr0mAPWjYJ3TLQrNCyD4YuMZa8Kw0rxm0Kzw34vwhYtF9Ari21NhC7WljQ5oaVN1WUhCCyEmyYZG5pWgBP1EWOYeS6Dk1LfwiMV5u7jDQ@EmPFCpffff/9rf/0t/uN//s333/v4vY@/@973v/3d7/zl13/9t775O//ug9/76w@/9dFfff/rH3/wtW9/6/1v/PpvfPP9r/34W3/x8Uc/@PqPP/7br//1v/369z784Yd/@eH3P/zBhz/68O/eKy7yveIi3/7q5Q9//vIvf/7y@z9/@YOfv/zRz1/@3VcvP/jgg6999P@5s9/8jd/6nQ9@76MPv/XjP/nzP/n4T//0a3/7/Y@/@4Ovf/Th@994/1d/47c/@NnP/h8)

I have an answer already that's shorter than this one in bytes - but I wanted to see how short I could make it in terms of characters.

## How does this work?

This uses 16384 different characters to represent the pieces of the data of the genome. This data is given as a hard-coded string, b, which is then decoded and printed.

To encode the string in the first place, the following code was used - it is not golfed, as the answer above is completely standalone and does not need the following code, only its result (which is the string b) :

```python
r="[Raw genomic data goes here, with the letters converted to the numbers 0,1,2,3]"
l=""
for i in range(16385):l+=chr(i)
a="0123"
z=dict(zip((q+w+e+r+t+y+u for q in a for w in a for e in a for r in a for t in a for y in a for u in a),l))
b = ""
for i in range(len(r)//7):
    b += z[r[6+i*7:6+i*7+7]]
print(b)
```

*Please note: This code may not work if it is copy-pasted from this website as it uses some unprintable characters - if you wish to copy-paste working code, take it from TIO

Answer (score 4):

## [Vim](https://www.vim.org/), <sup><s>2330</s></sup>2186 + 7476 = <sup><s>9806</s></sup>9662 bytes

*Saved 144 bytes by storing repeated character combinations*

```
i:s//AA/AC/AG/AU/CA/CC/CG/CU/GA/GC/GG/GU/UA/UC/UG/UU<esc>("s3x"a3x"b3x"c3x"d3x"e3x"f3x"g3x"h3x"i3x"j3x"k3x"l3x"m3x"n3x"o3x"p3x:set gdefault
@sA<C-r>aAA
@sC<C-r>fCC
@sG<C-r>kGG
@sU<C-r>pUU
@s☻<C-r>aAC
@s♥<C-r>aAG
@s♦<C-r>aAU
@s♣<C-r>aCA
@s♠<C-r>aCC
@s•<C-r>aCG
@s◘<C-r>aCU
@s○<C-r>aGA
@s◙<C-r>aGC
@s♂<C-r>aGG
@s♀<C-r>aGU
@s♪<C-r>aUA
@s♫<C-r>aUC
@s☼<C-r>aUG
@s►<C-r>aUU
@s◄<C-r>bAA
@s↕<C-r>bAC
@s‼<C-r>bAG
@s¶<C-r>bAU
@s§<C-r>bCA
@s▬<C-r>bCC
@s↨<C-r>bCG
@s↑<C-r>bCU
@s↓<C-r>bGA
@s→<C-r>bGC
@s←<C-r>bGG
@s∟<C-r>bGU
@s↔<C-r>bUA
@s▲<C-r>bUC
@s▼<C-r>bUG
@s!<C-r>bUU
@s"<C-r>cAA
@s#<C-r>cAC
@sƒ<C-r>cAG
@s%<C-r>cAU
@sĐ<C-r>cCA
@s'<C-r>cCC
@s(<C-r>cCG
@s)<C-r>cCU
@sŀ<C-r>cGA
@s+<C-r>cGC
@s,<C-r>cGG
@s-<C-r>cGU
@s÷<C-r>cUA
@sþ<C-r>cUC
@s0<C-r>cUG
@s΅<C-r>cUU
@s2<C-r>dAA
@s3<C-r>dAC
@s4<C-r>dAG
@s5<C-r>dAU
@s6<C-r>dCA
@s7<C-r>dCC
@s8<C-r>dCG
@s9<C-r>dCU
@s:<C-r>dGA
@s;<C-r>dGC
@s<<C-r>dGG
@s=<C-r>dGU
@s><C-r>dUA
@s?<C-r>dUC
@s@<C-r>dUG
@s☺<C-r>dUU
@sB<C-r>eAA
@sW<C-r>eAC
@sD<C-r>eAG
@sE<C-r>eAU
@sF<C-r>eCA
@s¼<C-r>eCC
@sH<C-r>eCG
@sI<C-r>eCU
@sJ<C-r>eGA
@sK<C-r>eGC
@sL<C-r>eGG
@sM<C-r>eGU
@sN<C-r>eUA
@sO<C-r>eUC
@sP<C-r>eUG
@sQ<C-r>eUU
@sR<C-r>fAA
@sS<C-r>fAC
@sT<C-r>fAG
@s¤<C-r>fAU
@sV<C-r>fCA
@sX<C-r>fCG
@sY<C-r>fCU
@sZ<C-r>fGA
@s؋<C-r>fGC
@sØ<C-r>fGG
@s؏<C-r>fGU
@sł<C-r>fUA
@s_<C-r>fUC
@s`<C-r>fUG
@sa<C-r>fUU
@sb<C-r>gAA
@sc<C-r>gAC
@sd<C-r>gAG
@se<C-r>gAU
@sf<C-r>gCA
@s¿<C-r>gCC
@sh<C-r>gCG
@si<C-r>gCU
@sj<C-r>gGA
@sk<C-r>gGC
@sl<C-r>gGG
@sm<C-r>gGU
@sn<C-r>gUA
@so<C-r>gUC
@sp<C-r>gUG
@sq<C-r>gUU
@sr<C-r>hAA
@ss<C-r>hAC
@st<C-r>hAG
@su<C-r>hAU
@sv<C-r>hCA
@sw<C-r>hCC
@sx<C-r>hCG
@sy<C-r>hCU
@sz<C-r>hGA
@s٪<C-r>hGC
@s۞<C-r>hGG
@sʬ<C-r>hGU
@s֍<C-r>hUA
@s⌂<C-r>hUC
@sÇ<C-r>hUG
@sü<C-r>hUU
@sé<C-r>iAA
@sâ<C-r>iAC
@sä<C-r>iAG
@sà<C-r>iAU
@så<C-r>iCA
@sç<C-r>iCC
@sê<C-r>iCG
@së<C-r>iCU
@sè<C-r>iGA
@sï<C-r>iGC
@sω<C-r>iGG
@sì<C-r>iGU
@sÄ<C-r>iUA
@sÅ<C-r>iUC
@sÉ<C-r>iUG
@sæ<C-r>iUU
@sÆ<C-r>jAA
@sô<C-r>jAC
@sö<C-r>jAG
@sò<C-r>jAU
@sѳ<C-r>jCA
@sù<C-r>jCC
@sµ<C-r>jCG
@sÖ<C-r>jCU
@sÜ<C-r>jGA
@s¢<C-r>jGC
@s£<C-r>jGG
@s¥<C-r>jGU
@s₧<C-r>jUA
@s֏<C-r>jUC
@sá<C-r>jUG
@sí<C-r>jUU
@só<C-r>kAA
@sú<C-r>kAC
@sñ<C-r>kAG
@sש<C-r>kAU
@sª<C-r>kCA
@sº<C-r>kCC
@sͼ<C-r>kCG
@s⌐<C-r>kCU
@s¬<C-r>kGA
@s½<C-r>kGC
@s¾<C-r>kGU
@s¡<C-r>kUA
@s«<C-r>kUC
@s»<C-r>kUG
@s░<C-r>kUU
@s▒<C-r>lAA
@s▓<C-r>lAC
@s│<C-r>lAG
@s┤<C-r>lAU
@s╡<C-r>lCA
@s╢<C-r>lCC
@s╖<C-r>lCG
@s╕<C-r>lCU
@s╣<C-r>lGA
@s║<C-r>lGC
@s╗<C-r>lGG
@s҂<C-r>lGU
@s╜<C-r>lUA
@s╛<C-r>lUC
@s┐<C-r>lUG
@s└<C-r>lUU
@s┴<C-r>mAA
@s┬<C-r>mAC
@s├<C-r>mAG
@s─<C-r>mAU
@s┼<C-r>mCA
@s╞<C-r>mCC
@s╟<C-r>mCG
@s╚<C-r>mCU
@s╔<C-r>mGA
@s╩<C-r>mGC
@s╦<C-r>mGG
@s╠<C-r>mGU
@s═<C-r>mUA
@s╬<C-r>mUC
@s╧<C-r>mUG
@s╨<C-r>mUU
@s╤<C-r>nAA
@s╥<C-r>nAC
@s╙<C-r>nAG
@s╘<C-r>nAU
@s╒<C-r>nCA
@s╓<C-r>nCC
@s╫<C-r>nCG
@s╪<C-r>nCU
@s┘<C-r>nGA
@s┌<C-r>nGC
@s█<C-r>nGG
@s▄<C-r>nGU
@s▌<C-r>nUA
@sՖ<C-r>nUC
@sα<C-r>nUG
@sß<C-r>nUU
@sΓ<C-r>oAA
@sπ<C-r>oAC
@sΣ<C-r>oAG
@sσ<C-r>oAU
@sͽ<C-r>oCA
@sτ<C-r>oCC
@sΦ<C-r>oCG
@sΘ<C-r>oCU
@sΩ<C-r>oGA
@sδ<C-r>oGC
@s∞<C-r>oGG
@sφ<C-r>oGU
@sε<C-r>oUA
@s∩<C-r>oUC
@s≡<C-r>oUG
@s±<C-r>oUU
@s≥<C-r>pAA
@s≤<C-r>pAC
@s⌠<C-r>pAG
@s⌡<C-r>pAU
@sʭ<C-r>pCA
@s≈<C-r>pCC
@s°<C-r>pCG
@s∙<C-r>pCU
@s·<C-r>pGA
@s√<C-r>pGC
@sⁿ<C-r>pGG
@s²<C-r>pGU
@sѻ<C-r>pUA
@s©<C-r>pUC
@s®<C-r>pUG
}x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NXxbT1vJtvX7@Qvfy2cilEYdFAS5bO6YAGkICZfEzcl@SehLTt@STpNAdyJ9ktsBgxVHzWXZ2AQBDr5gY9ObS0AbO7RU1eQBKcsiUkhHees/sr8xZtU5arKrYNWqqnkZc8xZtc7Yf/7zbcODs2e93rPeS2e9l896fWcvec9eunT20uWzl3xnL3vPXr509vLls5d9Z33es75LZ32Xz/p8/@eTigd1v1QM4@cL/HyJn6/w8zV@7uDnf/DzDX6@xc93@PkePz/g5y5@7uHnR/zcr/ul4cHXD//v/3z19Z3h0R8e/lfbA2/TpeqRlmGvF@1L0r5z6RLal6X9/eXLaPukfd/nQ/vvWNGO4FN/x1O2d1l6aduTJ@OrpnfJK70V25Nx/he2J@PmY7Yn4@afmt5lGTcftz0zX8D2zHx@2zPz5UzPZ@Zbtz0ZFyvZnoyL7tuemW9cel@IDP4ORmzPrLNkexyndm2Hw1TGdMzuonnbk1HBNduT2YIztiezBedMz@wuOGt7Zty07cm4qWXbM@Mc0zO7i27ZnoyL2lXK7jy2zVEV0v5SdnbKtjni9aztcEClbXPAn2YFX8quTts2R3xi2xxQZdsccGhU8KVs51Pb5oAzts0B1bbNAXrPdGQf@sB2OKLGtjnCnbAdDqmV9leyizrb5oBzts0B522bz18wbdnDRdvm8/@wbT5fb9t8vsG0ZQuNts3nm2ybzzfbNp9vMW3ZQatt8/k22xbtxfZtjyPapf217GDItjmiw7Y5otO2@XyXacsOVMl2OOAz2@aAbtvmgB7Tli1csW0@32vbfP6qbfP5a6YtW@izbT7fb9t8fsC2@fyggQbZwHXb5vM3bFvcI2k7HPC5xRIO@G/b5kM3bZvP/NO0ZdF/PbUdvlXHbIcj/vrNdsTcjP/fkYXfsm0OuW3bHDFs2xzwhbT/Rxb@pW3z@a9sm89/bdt8/o5pG8n/YTsc8I1tc8C3ts0B35m2bOJ72@bzP9g2n79r23z@nmnLBn60bT5/37b5/E@2zedHpP2NbOCBbfP5h7bN50dtm8@PmbZs4Gfb5vO/2Daff2TbfP6xacv6P@RshwM@LtkORxzlbYdDTp6ZjoGicMD2RHOTtsNBumQ74vdZ6XwrG9EvbEfGJG1HxqzYjowx0eVb2YzO2I6MydmOjFm3HRljsPdb2ZD@3XY4phyyHRmTtx0ZYyLAtwaTJmxH5rFjzH7StiNjgtL5zuxnx3ZkzK7tyJgt2@GY423TMfv5t@1wjHppOzImajsyz6LpyH7UC9uRMau2I86Xsh0JFgEjq@9kQye/2Y4sLmE7MlHBdmQis7jvzYb2bUfGbNoOx7zP2o4EQaOG74272DGyoTcl2xEwDE/bngzKW24hg17ZjuzowHbkMbPS72UPat125LGi7ZhgPmN7svOoiWw/mGAenbM9CZNOwPZknJO0PRkXMbP9YMJ55IXtybhI1PZkXCRie2acUcIPJpxHZmzPjJu3PY57ayc3CooYrf5gXCjy3PbMMqdtzyzTsT0Z5xhDu2u25@Rtz4xbtD0zzm97ZpxRx127vSXbM8tctj2zvQXbM@s0s9@128vanhmXtj0zbsX2zDizh7t2f3adZn@RjO2ZcWu2Z8YZpdwz@4ukbM@Mi9ueGRezPTPOqP2e3d@c7Zlx67ZnxuVsz8jFvsXszwnbnmFVU7ZnzGzc9oyZ2Sdlf@@itsNh7qbtiIMt2w4HuWZVP8reyn7bkTGrtsMx5Se2wzFvjHv8KPsqj9uOjEnbjtClmO3IPEZLP8qe3B3bkS1NLdmeTBS0HRlkAOhHo7Ap@wqjsFDC9gRoNm1H5BAyGrpv9BVK2p4MC6/YnoGAhO1x3JEBnvtGXaEp2xPn/pftGA4ctz1BBEMd7xtlTS3Ynkz26x@2J2vcsh0B3aJNXwRHsrYjU23YzuX/@n@//Oc/LcgujotwDiyoF76FVGdoSGX1hF4GdNTDS6F2ZC5IV7BvJBgQjLsDWYGNA@H0li7UdH92tZZ/xGjHD18Cdqi9XiQVOo9hP8ITsCW9qxMnz@6qf8E01abe/SeM@YrafQhf//EHvBT5AxIrQJkO6TUdxQy38achvYYV4VVAJ7zrKgRwlD8u9qp/fQncgX0iYcAyIIlTeK@b1ZuAKkz4elbvAN7U7skzpFbujge4hKYTQPrkzmEilVIbt/BGd@7KYQDTHxXghnxZdKoRDoLsQpWwQrXeDNcFOlWphN7F81@oHB6Nzql1vKwc1Gvd5SDWprZu9sPQvqi7ytVElnQQEA2WgO06ixRfdBYwpjc/Lrk71wCE36uX9dwuZtg7efamhAxJF1TuMTyV880/9XV4Py4hmxxRu3/ihfNqE@kWgBdib8T/6AJeWg6pHEDul1EIvHYIMsZzN3UIgfCmnqwZ4PuDkFGYopjBMtEPBxo9EO0XQxBVqY1ydRbPvA3UuTH10p3r/3PanWvTk9gf0jIuG3rLvp4d1StvXunUsNpDFomEFwaAd8XTak@VYNV6G69s9yG4wIgg5ei@StJS5p9iZclBdQCJzz/16gJUCzFnIMoVyNjdpGlFIJjpH1UG2Sr@G2qHLoYx6lE/NMX9RmI0DjRggJBWTucgrdg@5BFPXYc56BW1gfVESxVqA/kiJqo@3oYzQP4eiKy9EU9GFrFYOCOWeaW5q7UCqtMZdxWKiJTH8QIo2K9XPi7pSa9K6uV7Z8rBO6PlcbVRDh3l3wbeRTnWmcZ/3NhqTXkcCK4OsPb7D7/FLxAVMGF8pa6aT/36RwUm/2f1ybOGIZrAHpL0n72vZ0XfyT701BYsB56U8nDX80/1xPE2plAbcKcSZV64jt3DILYg2mjJnavGS1toQFu00vnxNrV3kWKJzvr41lDSiwfn43hCJpmh6eQwxp3roSLiNKwX8OhIZuDNK8SUT93Yfaw4OIfX@X6@8wgKipbGqNlNNw2BhZIVah92RJeO5x42Ue2RlN47KjzW6wM6NKpDR4W@8hNM8UCeWUcoBJoeBgb@9peMuUaeuxPYpBOu4YuCjtrVJThPHhvVWWiz/b9h7OUn7o7ao2z8EIfeVoAiB35/8kyv3YVD0cg2jfLGaMyRGcgkq7buatohYUh@iV3jnXjBZs1RQafoCujAT2drYStYpS69DegEMSuSb6FgslwUTAoyjbpzx0VMDJzBs5HEHQgioNNwgooamfxGhc5@XDoMjEHvsNh46pIXs8EkwgHg/ZkKulFoqksn@fRqOcTNTGWh91gRek7DRWFh4RUaClYLG42sVtFQoDBY/69/8D@ndAP2G1mj0xFBMjBt4hC1BzeOVPCl0RLMdRLA5Pgb6M@r@K@OqyA@Jj9VRfyJvwSgJX2q2NAtDuTUdMADOmqg5Ejeo/Y8gAjIK63H8U5aYAUk6G4CBp2SLCt2l0rEfPE0ENwJQ2fOtLtTCQFGYl7Pm1d0mOTjlpNnmA9AmVN7x0UdqkF68aBO8H@t/ETngXWrCC0wHW4odR5jAPylB7d63FUsYf5phSq2uXMaBv0UKte/92HqzgY@lnhcqdMqUw0J6hKsApKZ6XY3P@T08tDjCv07B1NDM5U6dA5bbz/Kl4ND@O33NYf@zp4hLKKV@sTcznQ1HriF5uvZJtE4JA0ziNMk92roJw40skK8ju17T5497uQKdulLsVLPAIwZ763yVnsHr/KZyGLjafzhuDjMquChH4YztXDoR8TCAGB9IDPSebz95hWMf@UxPAQyjWQplFhJZzxU5tRSOehOvEXY/USnOvXkCNU3lT0q0Gmi@t80bCDW/Hi15jrg8NAwzDmvCw3423Hxgt6B0KbiHr0z0IKdwNsBR5RR2W@0aOw/j306gTq1eaednkLFZGmYG7V4zaOGdpgSHDHugzMIDNFa4qkOGO78uOgk7K62jiCUAtdTx9vQpZOHvoBnK4iBsJT4qgnP80@xUQyIp9t14W1AdBoiUsLh3Cz8w3EnbsGmvAgtoSTpxhqcNJRiHFln5J3V6Q@5bvw1vFL2t6ndbu4ArpnVoZ/Pn6PEIMjpo8LrWVX0QYk6wag7fRgYoSXDLOe7YYgUXCCjIbq42qDDAFVhyNhMOFF7HTPrGDnBAQkc14cREUdv6uCpmpNn3rcBLyQI/BX5wcTh6uHEI/qHDsLfp@KQE6w9S3eN7rvpikZoHqi2K1tfvUNri5VuI6yFgHAjp89RurG6T2gYkekz2LQX7@YWykHsBy4O4Io4Pg/WwulmRWDGXECVoPgu/AuMxkIYHIsE8EUYF@QUyLgvWbWVaAsR68QvsNoGPYFYFU@Vx6uwcZWFuy2rEnwxgSk@YX6CHWEI7Any5WtBrWY0NeVrQ6cPboo9Uba52spy8JDPEWkB4yU4FexyGqGbulkEZsNcnJ0a/I7CBKxhB5Gcygxcf9hErFlkyCjpVD3dgiYep1z39Bp8dBS/exuwRgJWNj8OurICQ/isAwC/39wJ@4hk8A@2sWG4H@TnZkFbEmBkC14KNThzrRXyTxrR@ZqPi4eBhrJfUH5ZbZZDuuQC/xZUpgtyvQgnh0YQUyJp0XEWxCqUutDtrYF2I0td7gTFDDDAXJANjETv1g6pzXrCfmmAGyLOzmKx5@DdsOOLWMLJb3hZpS609OigegW8T34AouR9UK4H9DmLJKMW@8AeicWLqthMo8t2AlmxMnh8sn8Q6JnWk@3wtGX9goCD0O4IZ8VcV05BMifPzrgvdRJITDaKxS916dLJM3euk46eVUWEvfFhhKy3AZWAMKpo9YA27ANcDn66KcpQmw2y7@tYIxAwYkLgYj8fiu17xCBXsLJgBDYAGpfB69apWges1SGNJ4DFihKq9NYpBXj2YCp9MAa7AGKRSyffZynFaLgdcoX/hchYhq5h2FXBoGm8@T2WrLaATww0acIWJLqPP7TQWDAHlk8@u4Zlv54d6oQNTzJJQXZyjSrwv@iAFSOCIWI7i1xOBi6FDQMtY/s60QCQia9Ao9TlTK1GMgGjB9P6nbAzoXZ9N8lNdqCvELYanm4jveqmgqN5@BmFqjdH2rD4Wii5jdTMgDL4U9CpPY1UoRZOG8/dBnsGNullmOaO9wbZHvScbGVEC2G/MM9I/ND/Ta9egVzgSVMLCGPJeu@Nd1EBSgh8G79/cK0H6/sJxF2SqFX6JvKIpNpCcAFxTyBSF68Q4iRieVt6XpM5H2936QmOQC5WaD4FCT7E8qEx7gDu0EL@D8oTnWHas6InWUSQOJZ14VKLANfssKItnhshpQlkTvuYM41Ddtgv7AISJHlDPxhRRZErrALk0UHsyQxT3LABaCqQ6RSqvnBcfEj2MD/eClNvARrXN37JCdphI8A3RiYEOnottMfA5AhDkAQTLHhPH0jesg9vdXYeC3yu1ULHMCrYEmbCyyHdaDVzVD/rJ389xWbCK4ypzSMgc7myMZ8FbADqdUp67VPix9wjLLu5u20IXomoORWvo1mtCAOIWBKA1WAo6FowMjqsSxVi/iXxBpWtx/5jpffkmh9yPlk2U6M8BtJEzuvlowJTWryi2fM@6@68eXXhzas2oEF8VG1cVbsYj1cj3Vg2NI@r80tWtQ6Z8lQOvAYP44UV7ss@Ac2FC74W9yWiDxM4CHimGViQk4QElhIbUlsNFDxkQ8ozS3wJdugDSpvqgxGnCOmLNLYXvuZRVkqrGTgLJJkY45Q63WwbU8x9AXUhEEwZ9R5gb62mAc65iKx8kvGBJNHxato@zbbsvyr8JPkPmD4kGFm8inkApJHnfX3HpG/gEvFysP2UEH8h54/GIJBFD4HNBVThRUxEkcTNDOhoSzMhwgE5I8VNtzczPq3XI6OOr3/ibh4XH@iDKiHIWQkZ0wTFhcregRp3sxlLHmcU34Z0ruKVzWqPZk6Hxr8@MkxoYGpZZZq8iBPebuws@CGH@Im/wLXnnzYz2oRXBIBI8h/4YKVXqr4nq4ZenenWSoI5pbajQ2oLbjVFc2iDbC7UM2yB7MDMQUOYEtWOIl1PjQotl8rDKgNU/j4sHGsFi0qW/QjlyGtS1whN6V54phcegIioC@UnTUwIQqlKsKSpbJu7KUmE84W8L3ePxD3mrSA0g92UCIV7/YJQD7kBhwGOap0dgrrPdfPvYiHU82ItiIzaY3VhsUVcqgRCuDkMR5tagNDgm9HwcbFWIWr00zvhIbFiXdnv63DnLiCI1kEko@Unqvg20H1fyhTRcI8JasxdWEpqxJ83yFOOi8fbKoXJITqYcNAB@yzof7e1AQsPajsqGOroNVlJXtXGbVDcce5ph/hDa1plZgxr3T95dhjQeV/NVcmAyLZAPiJ9XjImhxYfLTFF2b1C9uu4O27MOEJ0/5hM1ZW6wyyoYXTuGhOBTF0n/xxxql1ZuKSnWEtw9rawFmbNbqxfhxDpI2utIjtY/uphYJgO9Vxtvp6VpSC1Il3KC4dLf6Z3mKrqCdiW4KWTZL1YJWA0CUFYckDke6V67KAXNiP1G3h2CAYNmA8Jh3b8zUIPR2AAiEM0lA0aWV7EjRdWUahJmBDy2ei43gMhirI@sSDJLFIo2vJTWBqrAZKNJPCwMz2MV3uYJ2EtU9lWWfQCZobBlIj9CwMnzxDbIA6IJUx0UVsenfLVm1ymGcuFE2fVbmsN49yi2uwapv8DuafijHSrbdRIXiI0C0PY8Z/TgHTsOQqarfdaDiUi52j@EYNRjsN3QJAQ2rdkI8EZn1RvcuTYNIO8pFnT94hTocQoQyTC3awERX@lp0qXaskgYMt7vhpEe2Rd40Ok1IwBVVrSlkjsl3ag71gDKcQeYACabya5XgKgqEz7LU4TnLkihkzlAsaYIpECzNWTX/nBKxEqmKl2wNLBZBJDmIF0nUxgB9gFf0I0OsoPMtNJ1OudR8zmsID4CgMtMRIOttUqgB0BttWazAIaCk8rktzkGEtMa3ofYTTT3ua@PHlWJXubrjuN50d06pDLJ/1R/xoY6oUpeVS2BgqXNMtgsMq4m0K0O4XcZT4dxDRCD/jyGE2Z8WemvxyswfQ@YS8OF7j@NvCIwu9XpfPA01ByCBEo8rwRSRsmqlAgJHhqn6RSpxQ9gs4ar1KJ77pkhqQQal8Vst2X3wJgYUTxNIioKRBlSdUcoPF1ePjJswa4N4TPmnKD3uskvgPcYeFwwfmnKsna2y5eq/cfwb7girEiQtZfv0E14yxJszgI06jAtMC/eFol3Dk3e08l2xQjpgm78H6Weko@Aje22XnyWzXjYmmw5qrOVnR2qETX9XKQiMlY7ANFjKR82EaYqQk9e0ukGoFnL/sYdrGhqA@2ojZG1UEL4QNgsalLb1410HpgNcVavQXDmYofwUwoz@FHkk/QJsOJ4@J5EOzIdHkcuDShDnToHqUKX6CwWXiuI2hsfVzymfreKUZ6ViOTeuuK@xKqhTvG10@elf1/TlewUpPUoSY3BtKYJ6hCfGGWWyMRkxg5Ti29e62JHKRAVUeSgOYsq9ePsJB6iaYieGeM1bgVIT8lEa8DC7lRTTaTwTIAd4he46Mqy2pAnhiY6wZ3Ibz4pXjotEHNkF0g4wOu0SgBXlFaDOYY@hbw4zx@JG7fQIMNMz9zSsRCrmvanTsq9EIH0a3rg3qFgcopj2Ou@dhQiyntYIGAtR3mxpN0WhY/s92AcwRQBP8eLCXu1zsXWPBdlrww7tNB4EFc7@mVvnrBWchzuvNt4IZJVMr@Vr0MTpKqE/I@7M55y8GjwgNm08z3s/29jLovmdPtdGhGpopGNzt0ZujkWcfoae5/QnjQHDAPYTJzxYf9M99K6iQyttXeo7xrQxrDRZK25GU@yaWWqKr5kXq9ovb@@k2HrvQPydHBtM5WkuJPSNEww7MALN0h4/uUjGPz0N9xpp0c3TF@3tOpC0eFUV2ocCfeE7wauf34KgtKGLvaSOgNUYSbN925a3WPqGZ/6Ur7CPQxla3rIWW5JgXl3H1EceAbEsTGCzDlUEJvX5RaBRAw0FjJglBabQ5Bf@5cCw2QiZxUKfGrfh09ecbqOM8sgFX8G6RB8sY0HPuNlUDnVm7TeYLOl5USDBIfcnfR62Ktp6B3kP6lGumpCILOELTUrvLw6yj1MNktpYZ14qm/pNPuXBOrQOmbpqIlRRsJ8DDs6R4ysxegNFvVDMklIBfWuaPWR2pIgWL7dUCKUOqQ1WhMgwgVz5VDIvE5ojMUG175kOuSF0aY@bIID8SRgqmOHm@3SkoNYpCHMUNUJSgbUsK/8dTJs3adrq@quYyBg8Kl/ULcU4JHPHSJmMWWg72dgsSLqqS3j7fPv892wMvhOfDImX8oOeXCY6R4189dYEaMgHDoh2euIgjJORoXwdw/zZCMhU4aq4Pl8OBgBtbu8fKM7sB9@ddvH3IQJ8tWvFkAA52QakXyZ7DYaL6RJbqETjSSU0bHfSwAHNAXwDwWkf38m6txSn/9pla7VO4h/SaE5@rO6FLZX2@YjngmoHVjpHVEyLNfqp2IwB1eBJFkAwsZQqDIILeYuT/VKdYBRx4MNVTgJSw/@oUVpd6zjMnwDJARQi31TsAIeKRzl@ipMtfk2HF5SBK7BRFDhDEcQWTmR9aWoLDAANKDOZVoK/ul4FtRp7a6sJM2@GQI7CBxVKhlnrSuEkJkgUqx4o3zLd/AktQfUpOCud1HZjGoC2rTSytwSq0QZGP/F43lYBvR6eXjgUpzGvYuKgqYZb02A1u7y1Qvhq0hs/yjuoaALVmdyUDBNSVzG5cCW2pYZyBP@sOuPuBqp1mloZ22s/ZckgxnXqe5jEjG85lOskK3KGXDsv8noWFMpJnrx9WuynwOR0T4AHvZdLNlf6XecjcHCB4xJPnNzJLiD2qAYXQQMkIkC5mH7qr3vNoi6Sej4zsDUuV8n@URR@D1bJUcgTFH9Pc2U9Gh5LlHSP1WfEygovuet/QFLYCY@YxAEFeJ@paHtSRxQec@ARV7z755dfJspJPAVyJRiJp/6fSclEjvGdUspog1h8@o7HHx0H/odydgvXNyVL1q65wMynFa5Cw8ABYTiX9N@Qed0Z9qMXQQ2M@kMQ5F8GaGsGM4M2gN6DQQmdX4r1WRZeY1KHAEnospwSqZfTrtUoD3qaRY4A7ri/C98PQpUo6ETkuhLwNAAf6HulVWb9V57zX3HQZGeQbmziEuxf2NAzXteuX17C8UdoCVCThiGMSbhNop@ztP0SNj7RBgG0y58/Tx9sNDxtijvN5r0y8YFWDh0TDLdjMqN9TMpRCInHMsnQe8N/HmMGvfU0stkr@kzdnQ8TZBJN/IMB3db7rl4Yk/0zcWh@uQfMLLEDwl8w@ukbVN63QVxFDjxjrITvMabt1POrCKeMN5b5B3UDax3srj7SFSs8yIrbKEUgPcG5bLo7vpQbw9VurmKVH4sT3RSpfHKXg8cIe6nh/vgp4hSYgxMlpxrtJY/im1AYK3Cu41e57rjc7CJ6binTpU9y5a9ksShTWxvgpr8jTWY7ERnkQigLG8KMUm6DHyXPTUTi/cpNFnoZIg/ZRV/tKpsh92eOi/1YC1uLExTDIvVA3SOYOolG4mxoYDJ88@1xN98PGLPAuWEy/knsjlzt/z9mBjhoaloanozH2mGiLIEIbh9Wr3MHCBFdrMYx7PZCUzmJPieO5aRRWyhhAmRADdZ/Re1CmYKAFikaJlMlaLEIhUhOecLx5LMSvzqSkUKyYtiIrL/IcPcGXwGOMW0X3KlsxusRkGPnntns60/u9Z947UB79k6n9B7XbRoJBZLAueLl5kdHEcHXRjN/A0U9lEj7jilsiWZE7iZlULY3@aw6@rpJTgB4A6gUyTFCjIKHkeNO0VCJMVRrJ6nDV@OSF/86ptqFmvy3GvlnsAIcmcmNHlpUw4586donMV1MaVCqJIJFkFzbFqyoRf6haURdKNCYws82wCSSow7zUrITyX7peCER03OHNKlTyslMoJL7lIksWzPBY9HzMIv2PiqlBsBNASHo0HAMU80VlluJ8@Lv6TjElOG82VCcH1VTnkB/zB9FJ1eq9xQOjpA8Paul7PdvNwoOXjEjPnpSFhbLl30UpNLhGRU7opCWWRvJd@nmCqg3et8W58r84wEUkAPZxF8F/aa5uOVrHkedPd/OXa20BdFUwY7gXq/ubVKGsqyCKwH3rQaKWsMiAl28jSm1f3f4H9Ip9wGL0xZbIGOxlq0S/EN30U/EusaACEfu3LP6cJoStyutggJZKkuwOWtN@gNmrUFg@t0iylBDJ/To@@Dahdd8fEABY5QD4ydwbMLYEzXQ8h/Aqp/CePCgxQAU@DFMOn1XpPP8NOdIqSncq@AY27/dhkAnIGn6hBtGAJN8MiAIssiHTmNOECU8aSLnmVVDPiAWZOUN8s87RIDEuhmlYVAeecSqmE2MawMLLZm@Cgm16doPXzRII3iaDuVIVwu1tyJrJP5A86g2Oi9enWC70nv1WYOIOlnid@wkfh4fFVLCXKsw@eNu30INi6sZYbSG@oyvQ1TZeNldzNc6d0qaHD@Cmp6oFcv7lOOGaSMHRc7HgsqD/bi/dJcQu8Za@aZIMscoa4AkKGf27VqL1uo0UyCLpus82oES1Y@IDJpMr@0Qq93scw8kQdsNKf5kx5KQ6ySEDy6OSbacWlb3gqXkssut8P3RLwqJNyiBSVcfZhhQEcvJz2sHRcvILtwW7CvbwnscLyKDxy7kE1rwQhlywdBmq5z7TK9gilnxHQ@MPNIu2hCHbMlawMsqiX7UAEmALez0xqRaVqK/FLvthP2si8ZZ2BgGqUUyJBAZXr1wV3Ve31SYGBhB9W4@WJYHBG/653EDVYg8yUn5yiR7oxle3WhR7ga@Y2JutrhQG859UOHkREapF2HBfLTwh/z/npj@HV1dwdHJ9BeaWBUXyN/PmgX1KFfgH/FZJErLHh4dvAw6P8dZ7uY/Xz8bdAEjc7Kpc1RglPxQZqE7kMq8PMoQJiKJyv31R4q1iYWoMLgvbvf44/HRW@bKPZ4kEetMqpzBIxMtFc4WbdiVEd6tJR1t1W2zUpbo6HqKwzrZ08Ax8IRlrLfjGXVCXVmTkM@HjJa0FMNibZef6DVI4iszzGq4R5vQa9qufOkc5M3paggJiyK2dzUrTb6R@4jldf8fHiSQqi3eC1gqK5p6EyPjl0TbqmQDTLbIQVKh6Oreq9t4EeoR7NKjOClCVGMHF4evyTDsrtHYF0ScvF@iC0OVjEuyiDLIy2ofxkDA5cYMlyi1cAzGHJfvmJp/YWcsRgxMckad3m747sfl5LEivRkB6y70HIF5g4YOl3iYX@sMRPSGuVjCMp565@bh2pxUuk8Zss@uc4WZyx60juSDqBAXcV2dwrvPWOpB4gTUvmSJ0evSVD9lmimwdWckN1rCKq/AOvXkPM7ZJj1PCoFE9oDMxQS2r3tNxFWKGTZ78GGux0w3QjPibwOo9/17G4U3J1aYXe/W9YCaPbcwn6JQJDQG7WyTH4uMJyqz/ncbLmpQmWpBIDEJqmod7zdsnt0P89spXzGkY5HpBjp48l9i6Ip7DcAoLeYdz4c3KdZBOp3hMhMog4gQwMc@6oANcKTpsz4gqASiNLtC/O/8SEbc2nD86Rp7MaN3/M2woLoFSGC@z8JPfH5JQbEpdin691FKnl3lXLhWP712BajWB3NLDnsFX/W4QBKW9jIYz2C6R0PNMBEO1c7MCQepPhSNlVYiBvDY2aY@ujwnERumGOJ5dM@8VuwEmjCM@hpLkV13FfB3UM08QaR3heyYE6iMjRorM18LJwwEs8LZ7jmYUg8Q5vdYLBirOFAU7TY0QAVkxyBOXVAcltVmBKvBI6fV6vES6dkk8V5VCT/sXz9J1e6jQBw37Kq0tIEyHa6BzcYBJefFQArCK/9KsNAOUTvcvKBcT/6x8QRigx5L68dkUMO63y76ItJHRPmv8OzrGuMmLuKLVXSEJLCgGy5zgq60FmSfeCMOfH26uq9CT@AJyOzI/CRGp7QLaW9TYY0ATT@cUxCZoR9a9@5gz@0jCML@g0w21SffU6OXBcbGORys8g9Osf7dd5t2f8XJPoCuQH9If8jVQnSwYH2a53Mr3dglhHJVqX/Q3moPkS9tpyhqyFtBbSpChTTEojyQsNJiHHNHqZV2pmq8VJeGfMO/R6lsXiNXH1VWSFk3jTELb8RaccCDJZF1JB4OQ58kPaqCnrLGO5N3irDYq9CZTmMSePfnnNZlkO00PJ23LYTm2MyftKvF/MQ/9J8Y0llfUhTfIwnielqkpTcDf1fqdKjCDcbtTe5JElL0fw/lGTknjDxHiKt2LlcGGVMgQyhKffZ30q8YAXTr7Qmas3PW324nYgM2IuymLVB0LkyeF8xIcnKumDSh2n5bqXWmVBUW/XuBM9@F0r7y8s1mI@j9oDy4mM6SiLvjwZmIR0vb1MzbLeesRYvSJHcljIeZiY3Lcj@WyFIXSpP0TE@xLLYZiROUoRe86SWhCtVtrk3HX/ePucJB/5Czxob9clD4NiyZy7xvb1@m1bWV3uJT3wlz4uwd54EZxWM88EannooV6Xoyh6l1Txt3nEUGLayAp7d9l/612UVacaXiXaoyuHA@bCGK/a0hSSnhFdImTPqozgwbrE@UXWC3LEbwkxwOB/wy@BNT4k09d71EYf5ZzRk/rFIdlJfJ0neTxESbSIwl/I8TdMHkyMJjlrznU3m2reRfktDDTU8C7qxszpICTeWElWtCXWygRkjmSDV/VPfuvlPXTkJ4BJvJ1PT0usJbjs26OmFONqgeEddGW1npoJV5eDyg5YIk1w6FErJAnh@vZh3uHS41L3YcEwTI97CeV0DZtwwvJJwGcOmXVpGPNcEA7gDH4@YmPE4iDkjZR0TzKOBbrQhrl31a9KRiAbbvaQV/Ii9CpmxDO0vmYm7bH9oaNCE7wHb9ipZhQCb1jlShh9UypbxuqGeDNuB867y4TrgdyCi6yXn1w/5QFgTsXL/hZV4rEfAA8hMMGEgGlErzlbp76dfC/LnJu6dOF9Vq7DlLoY@Oek9HhUePNKT5godxjQkyol/sCMbwbOxDyeVw344cNx8Zx65c4B5ZJDUFbD2wB5ytKAKvbynCP9ELbZM8ajjv2fkd788JmUSwIPpXoBpcZYpCmNUrGTYDoVeO6qJP8j9F3se2rh2uftPkoqDMqhMj144sFVCK@B54@sqDlyvcR9OWCu0xNkeOH@CuzEB5V0Nl31yXWRcQJCcI32lZJr5MwWSY1SXlXqoB1rcGt/e/txsZ3QbfJbJkBSe8IoH@Etnm65cfECJNDRUc07JDpZ7@HRDRyKh@oLlSRjfUKLcrwkraNydYM3D14zC@cyu/BeKDk4Dbsq@Y63h91YF@8up3UaKVQ81@1usvavViUfX/dguXD44Az@RTAtfsi1tFtYDGQQKpD@Fc4RfxhXkyQzi13Mb/iFC6wnvuJtaxschKqYN/P6G@jKlkcvX/9zuqabd2SLR4VKQZDkIN7RVSWSipBTLvL4v2oQjt55VKjxcYlIh3NHhR/VXjuk@6mpOZDwVJefICcj0Uy6E/yqgtkGq4Od4m6OTvDKPmQQDrgxc1/M5Q0sibggcW8DHrmR6YVl7/mkZg8aGcnXS/khZ4ETHim5khzgsQy60Mwp8cTcm1cdXv3iqDDkxm6rpNrqb/Jq3jXM3WcwZAKveDajcl28iEH7mh8/lEwJoP4COllveXBKWEgoIVcpjvJyfAFL2VZbQ/jLVT45gTw2eBtSPCXHzEm9yQqeY4rQjDIr1/oIRLw7DrK8@wisBxQzZsJ3rNjqrWiDHd6CpKvLch05JjWglUd9DA@zFUDQLA@bfgeIwHGx4v0mVrw25CbEDNZQBXhDcjZ@jqcNRXMPGOkfj2d0BvwoYSoWzMtfyQcLaut99vaHnHzZ4s7pHK8vr95wY@1CWFsGoO1aMCBPk6Cn06BFtnjvr3IYEAVU62SHkHgQ7UAjHHS4x8cXvyBXDX6NDdWBOo/9rEvfuTvkfZtvWNPx6MmjvK8Hj4WmvJRXfGWMRJ@89c/pR4NMBJ578PArD9xxC0nFS2DfcXFMlXy8gDr9IefuABrm4zcVEVk@9cBiDjgtEWiPt5V49oAlx3MN5pMpPADr4QHD83bMOAAjyDQOCXtgedDdqTPHNMG5UQaBJVORlEKYXu6E5EAKA9U6REBY1QejDLovGh70WESdfuyVLzjWeQSHpOCpfEfA1wcj7oSn29zBx0uvuC/HyCKRWOQZSeX2qVwv5@QzerkPeq01dZ4GHZX7yvzi6KjQ9Q@gA0@n1nWeecv6VXr5i04qOsQiXg6LfyAJ94zZPq8o8OMEqrFZ7l84znfwNr85I1w8J3XhLDtTcR9srHSf5rIsBweL3acvMtSkmZWk3waA@NES7SVHYiOfZ0UirIoV8QD0vnxcfHRfziLSj1vxPswTmmKqESgHR3izm26NSMNQK2c@jqO3tSAqYDwJmEgP3jUy@kknqySPgW/n3LlOvX0YkKsjaZUdlXOjkgvX1cv8f/RBlWYGe@UC8AwTcCEULASkfLfcHXCJG1guSGBBavIIKh9yrPPzNDaeJjKm7pp8H4Q46PIi0yT522QzDOeKXOKNIaguC0WDx32Drf7E6u688XWSluzIAJ0jkrx/HV1YMutgcZ059S3tM2s@ZZO7aFNVIrgcry8h34qOt31kUtAnVRnWAdRuh84wAu5wXEqCb5@Ib1aopr2emdeFO4zBgV7iKYWJNcoNYyeMR3gbE5Zb2wLr6VESV53AVZ06z2LCgrmK7Cyy7rEKVMrW/6T5aULUfLCTfT17Xu5F7LcgcV9n7uA3J2BQ2DJyxt1r5sgDT3glbYz7u@kna7Xn30Xxy0qd/HNaZZoqeRyz80U/kz4IcCou367VdvMyBE/IWZN0BgnzDNmJIZ5A8WRyGG4O8W1f@0rlWnkT9SLFmKhtVxvdel1uv3bDJRd8fMeLsv@N1Kl5Xz0C8rV4/8YF5mf8JS94xHo6eFTWYWr176KdPp7Ru0hMzTlNbTc/tCx0t1ecqig/ARSWJO0HPwmzfu07rbJurFVPkuQ1Cq/OozkzRgiKId@dqHXnPPzW4g/ZrHyqxSSJ/DYNN72A7FInwAtSHaZ@x6t@B83migLxONkMfA4hv30bOAxADbSktZEmWjJ46J7efOiVGIcEUXjmDGxPUA3U68Ln8oXmP87fxZ/qWM2RT3yCM8dFxtgyo1lwRta0xOxlUnIOtfnTqE564BT5C7Sf529ZCUHiEdvv4ybaR6QoW@tmL3HqLxqxuDvCwR1V1JkxnR4CBO8hpK3wjtOLq5e/If2Rbz@nLslXtp/X8mw7xQmfIxI86h5q6gCYBWeE1U/9cujvIBufbYHeOnnd5UUlr9nyc0uYXnCNQTCQuQHLR9Y1D76Uk9QWqUeq/uogE2V@FQT7ARvd/rh0vK2TH5c8N5vII1b5cZTQ8OiMDj6Gs0TlOuCg3JJItemdv55CMfLtAl5JUFuXCmzJc4u8gDdHyuNeEXH4jkY473nDw3QE9qikRuQ7faS7Bzp4lb/OSh7be0XvXYZRvIuy2u80fVzqfFOSYxIa9ILaQOSKlf2V7twNPfl6tr35o1RA9mXF4x3H28KvEyM6y8@/4HuFEZ28pXLeex9y3dj4tU7IoKtK/QtrQUq93iN3FPKy5DSoTP6GfgGl93ToF@ZjLLz31z@41/SbV3SYS59g@Z/I9zBTpuKit9ydJvhv1/AP/Mg2WPY/kIrRTJ@AIxEidVHKPyI7IEnCBy4Rz1Flazp3rZ2FnDnJCk9LJTpg8hI8/iliT3bsNOzmjl7rqcAT7aBPklyGppimwtyQXaffRds7eR15nNi5elXbg7VeXpmM9fdcZ3EuB42Hp8/LbQrwqrDvr9/oRnJfgNdDtgDbu1Kg2f9Fvs2WO2c8dQs0my8jQql3UV7crZegJ0ULJ98C29gn5X96vH1dMtDUV8fb30jI/NuJAZj8JX53Esjgwd/leoILeLxJ93gpZ0h@1nbAXi8SZVd9ZIaFk2d6U74yG/fa//tP9dj/Bw)

All possible groups of four characters are mapped to a character in the compressed string, which are translated back into their `ACGU` values with `@s`. `@s` is a macro containing `:s/`, which cost 10 bytes to make, but saves 256 bytes. I also used `:set gdefault` to make all searches global, making `/g` unnecessary, costing 13 bytes but saving 512 bytes.

Edit: In answering more questions with Vim, I learned about using `<C-r>` to paste text from a register. From each `@sX/XXXX` statement, I removed the `/XX` and saved in in a register. I then inserted these strings into each statement with `<C-r>X`. This cost 112 bytes, but saved 256.

Splitting the string into groups of 4 leaves 3 `A`s on their own at the end. To ratify this, I added an extra `A` to the compressed string. This `A` gets expanded to `AAAA`, so after expansion, `}x` moves to the end of the string and deletes the extra `A`.

The compressed string is given as an input only for readability; it could go in the first statement without gaining any bytes:

```
i:s//AA/AC/AG/AU/CA/CC/CG/CU/GA/GC/GG/GU/UA/UC/UG/UUCompressed String Goes Here<esc>("s3x"a3x"b3x"c3x"d3x"e3x"f3x"g3x"h3x"i3x"j3x"k3x"l3x"m3x"n3x"o3x"p3x:set gdefault
@sA<C-r>aAA
@sC<C-r>fCC
...
```

Putting the compressed string in the code does not seem to work within TIO. However, I tested it in Vim and it does work as expected.

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 9830 bytes

This contains many unprintable characters. Below is the structure of the code without the data strings.

```javascript
_=>(g=n=>n<127?g(n+1,s=/[\n\rACGU\\`]/.test(c=Buffer([n]))?s:s.split(c).join(`...`[j]+`...`[j++])):s)(1,j=0,s=`...`)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LZpnc9u81rUnPZlk0nuP4957b3Kjrd5u1SPpSKJEsYBgBdH/@nlxP/PqgzwWSQME9l5rXZStPuqHw8D0ohUX6qP/jU/@1zs5nTdO3JNT93hjc@/MmHeXNpbDk7X2f9z/BKlL7Z///Oe/nbXVaBRG88OTi3g8HgXzbbezsHAWHoaroeeY6sDCqgVNd/6/TIhYCiFDOSLhGElhMpsM@UgQKWyp3jiXrvohJ5ylOJkQLlEsqS@4DDkN2D@Bx3zJeCQET4lUkkqERJgILP/h/2j0H8o0qQ7wf8Q/qct/UvKfVOqf1D//bVudpf/GXsIgdhzNv6RUox7QHAYvA83EEdQwoUHox5cMRSGi0k80LHCiXXKmkVhccnWBe3mpXRJGLmPKQokuscak@kRcskiqM1PapXqRS43@@7ngmjqm/d/YS0tqNQ7DhfmNZetkXS3ef6NvcnIq98y2sAowo7nffZc7BN3BhaOz2xzbsEFtCrB5my6ftNEgp2FmZjXa3iDXDqA2GIwzWlfjfRprrmsw91D9@vrM0r7tNs5jTGIvAzX6M6t14Ut5rA9M59cd2Hh2@/agq3mmSaR7bt99cmUx@Yhvp/wA9@iv3/EnDOneiDtuU3PGtQ0ILNIgiWxgw0tTuBHYeRqON3xvJdvhXTUISbxfonxJb6VlXzhqWXfhGCHT8Lx4baD9UlN7Q6LS1K87A3/kcztB5AQ/PcgQS6Wpp9/TOCQ1jRuPxu/tMiP2aCPVhg739tbtMP5OQVS0nPQd8JDh1Nh@V4PQW93M7ppjPgnBsbo6MRKR6ndCNoaaw/8aI9E/sH4virpdXCxZzv2x4N1FPCTxSRRXScA@F4Ix/tszcGLL0dh/orm560va14j14F3hwXEG/kmCM7fu8aaT2AfjXxGWxYd9rYJv2Uql9ObimIXYGwz2emBb9uRm10jmn9Dg0OLG2vdYE6dVfnSLe3He0dBrj3zcjN9S@0zt6k4Hx6l2cBZvjmfvQNpupw4xisvmdodezGoX5KRUcLAod3vnxU@u2OyUFtjJF@pqcRRh220RMMsC8Ntrnn17G1WNfFPUsehyD7WKA3EhbpC4OPbEpMMhFa4IV7pEvoiA2mGwsf3MrTgk/vi9CUjP4UDTB/QitidtEfqNCrn6zPgBqddGicNcHt2G7SMfIy8OI2Z62w7FH2x622678pbpox4jzVjr4rqNAxosjC9maEaeszEei/pJdE0KHGAu6mTsMfVucfBt8eKcOwf5BRujaiRv5Rkokeso1fEMtFqMceWQN6Mc@7j1vv6qyHUxdx401dgkiQkK4vjvoutMvafN1b2rQIfUDPD3nx6PwkJEYSH0@c32TTfV6YQW3R/Csb3T3xBuMUv/hmd7fQuNGu2mOHWypGiPgQW/DWRnPXu2FoCLQUDPxPUqhjj5Vq/S8GQlAOR48gpDMn4VoIQ6WnyGb2ktV21KUKDXXAwGFvPseuQn1KMjOyyHP9Yp8VYW6rbDUqNNJxPGXZqYSRBc8PqXIKD7NHbh1oh@Db8kkXWBrLcV7/gDAMQpfAmMIAhSnakkWfvU5J1PwZ1NucmODmD4ufkYm06BVM4bcGBR7BxsBlz4Ler9QHBQEqryo17toO4FN@gbKkDq4RNAY6GfymbDNHnfpPFJVbPDtjiuBfhoPVK9FiLPWi16mudjXd6Ms0d9lM05CSbjvQePvn1heejIgIKdXuvIuAucsG9FkWt4w7egFE/CvNyl8swvc@fjAxJKI7dfFS4ZsSbO3LS8BwHl4ibA8K9rr0TxGzOQQRxN2ryILFU/8PxnkFS13paBt4NgACHxgubuLLn6iQdysskicXvkzNH8Mfs@Vaozl2VksVjrpiYT39PWsRO81x8B7snyZYiKtnfLQi5qaU0Y@/TvMTyopJYfDuLX5P1CY8BmTGoXr4DsUY6CYznIn7pDl6CVm0DkO1AnnQrQqKj1WY0GTWYviuPcmdd8E69l4CQ0NJRafj3shcF77uGoAfxoINUOIAh5WiOrLsw@0lyUNL8PxDHD9qjNEvskUvsAyHgyou6f4rHxKqMTx@I1nRnasifdgdJEBK0vMJJ1YbnzfW92maY63c8eOwoZPJz4FaJW3uTVgE@GWR91T1kUW37ji3QtWTqSQdbJ7J8HqjiGF3oIqc9gVOhm7QB7LNkqpb4ySN924Q@vYawPkEAFUnVYcoFgtNOy0HqWPNum9m8anmYhn/OfetphmBAjEm4WFT1RfhiceLLtDEXDpkp6dRc/BPVHrAvFGsXBQtcCJAxqP66MC9vjN6D9G6y6U3HI0e7V4Yo01@V5U6wMcAYmccXP9//S71DzzhBUs4PGQeFSBuOZGz0JG3Y2swMru9@4Q8uX@JmSLnYT9q79EJqUWL931KQsC7wcQXnTCKMQA38lZB6SFuXe/DJLTdrOm@b@pL/GxmBpUOy@FOG37pCNk6dh8ScdMFioFuhAVlOdxvb@K1G/t9thlaiqFdmTH@TKKDx28any2dT1ZdO@cbRqK9gf8er1IliPkEUfebKqCQs4ATVkcRBl4tJJY9273Yyq2TAbk1bwzUD1QdXalLfJo3cQvYnvli1lfB6fPMPkrcF6McVNV@S1/ST88lIFGvv9/er3GGiBiwr0z5fA93rd0zIt3jlYVefZz1MtwIcHUfnEMkTVX1i8CsxOnKUuugU7Pnvik8EwEBbiFdenQ3O/t9cPSUOmgS78XIzH5Ukaydpu/PRREU@FMGyvDdhYR5amTyOZGsU/yJKc9MPH03LgB6HI@xVhuKNYY@EkXRShHtDcGEWY@NR2IvTjC7FQiyDGq6lh9W1LxT/9@NBZICEp2EAe6ic59NxOYmcw7Q3OA3uofDtEOTbpF8Jpz5mcYl/PTXnP88@ZdX3pPG9OwkUrIm7rwThqg9/2VP/ca92mJp@fssMWGYWdug2Oao9bxBj2aRj9oMjB9o53gk6@h6IRx1pEjK9TYtp1JHCjH8nXvzsgwb5yGuS4EI8SnTU15BswoBtiGm6eeDq96LYS8gJ55htb9pshE53H@mNeznPg@WE0pOtBXztneP7VQmAJNBdyixJn4Gp4Tb/6cn92zl3arxreVsB2iiz/50@EH8mDwoqB2gyZTj0eCn2txRvI7Z0FRy7oEUMjeviKGDu5wiTUme9SO6K59Q5fA@OgT2VP57WBdvLsqQtbUDu932NbkPl9COgNh/2iOOvKA5GTbthSN2ts2MF4H@dp4jffJBiL3El93j0qrQWDW20No/bkBbEm7SL@mWT3NG51AN5kM@AXSQ3f2Wa6R@dhqr@f@go1WYxIQuqEQ/jspyhrPgCoKNrSagWYJQCGPgvwyXYbFlPp1WDsoccnqINvqKwUBwzrcYv3wdAZorbFnUT9JcTKpafKgdzUYTmwNxueSqalVNp9Vcay327WeISzjeexoXmeL8uoJAy8V0/1ASUq79DA035vHHvy@PYuNWQfIfJKLRARafm05QPaabt61nJ/yjUaspIE0DWwjm3AxbRovak53m5MT1ObO@VLMe1fOLy/U1zS9kpZbQeQRqKgIV/ptq1TfOHo514b/s6vhDP23UfMiy698fSz69D3/GQcPhI8iq5ceWrSp9ybqXEV8AdotGQx5BQmHfCWpa4Nd@KnPW8zfa357STGcTjcMZ8Hhuxw8YokPo4XwqVhvEPybJrobYsukby0PP2zruQqxCr/uwO0nmlJg6U@U6@x4zDr@WnGS7VFX6auIz7sMmFEZNJxnitdQ@d3M2TB07vPw9/KQmwOrJYuqvTB9Zu@5q@DoUUGtlj2y9Igcnk3DIZTnnG/DNPh@Q3AmLjELtpkq@TQNjGddUeeFiwmLHJtEUP/t91oL7GjPdd7g9/jr2HQxp6SiVU4JvIWJ3f@Eu8GLOGuSvhfWE0WLpFK5yHJa7sEkWqm88r2EHcgeS9THZZ/0cPT8kZe4LKKGt1dZu1OdvcdO18wr1jrpW7gwX3Hcj39VHAwMvcq88Ng7ETxieckns87LbgWJYznSEtnNSv1tWJBjzq126tVetFuNazf@MpuGuzG8MJxFg6vTnRpdHBoA73aODC9DDnSolMGVUxeiPHtKAgrSYG0WWAlmJUPLZIBpOk9jrUWTY04cKK/YgB63uj@nSqesQ/kkAZJJbR@J1gevCOmvtotAsr/wqNgHDIV7PBgvoI/sBZt0e55uOWRfaf1e9Q7bp3K/mg8TPVHBMi@WJe5ZtWuRX90XeqW8/0hT/84@Uomoxj4eMxr2jBhjU7qKy77Mue1blDAuJ68cI0ZnaHuDjMCeDZKGuDwnHvZHZHD2Q25TOWwgcBzV4WmbuLZRFb/6B/aITFnBjCXtLyYmput0Rmmm3tDx0m1PRR@oHwZ@HIzM2UP90M8eBuT30tKqcPnrEQ6@ihapZmQmfR5ajJ6wt6zkDyMA5FeUwLe/BQpdhjzzq2w8HXRfzhNCRI5mrwBzKXKdf5Q2Vch7dw/cl1U9@yts66yV1HKE2m8KYdf4v3e/QwLM3pfdmvvwQyrsht5FoiacnzTLgxuJn5Mzp/LvVk39cKQ/RCQ4GbHoDbvI4/nv2BHxTMcBGRf8Fvk8gq3NF6jcQ1qu52/ic3dm9G9B8tXtqJhkwWm/XfggxcH756yF1PFTpXX2CcYufBdQBtY38OwekoG0KBxE3mYlC8PJm2WWla6d9YIYRTKmmvUPU3MQRP7NbqGHjtwii/Sr@yJhWS6ERNZbxsLr@MnILd4JRA3prq8z55dJd/B8TgMWRP02Tp7p0ljEEIGv2nm4X7YZ/qcFoVmxFVu8qO9Xcob0AuvJ6@gV7DwodSvshYyu2@@DCehHH6LmgW0Zn4NO75MH189I@GNhwCkwfHxE8iHboar4pqpAWQMipGb9r3XrHDEENaDBE9nmRd6L23RpgNrHMTiqxuI7lsPuNo2mT7W8MM1d07MITPCpZOL3VGoQkkIMUClmHuaHKz2spTwU42A8cj7tmPPYO7C7q/CZc2hxFCreaS1EHstwZjvArqnkYGlAc2@@uiH6xuT0LR/MzcUvErTnuyjKEZNpMTHng3ExV2QsArC@cG@ryJslmVI@xQmQbOyvCQv6l1DbThLPsjd50IZd6lxqkLc9d0nNQIqM3FLrQ3yQu7aEVZpFZeY6tkyni8/xutJFG2hb8wbRdjv7dHUZMh@TZ7FUJocatNafCP13lX45CyJa5oqu83OdCmiCu7dLa@tLiJjHpGysO5i0/fo7Laf/5GvnxxPhgVsmbZsg/P5BGdLj4rxIFL2FOm90Qc2Vhn8BJJ9S/txoiTDPShf3hN1HepeclXLgzpoLugyT17pe1YYyI7F/JVearjd0ONoJgO98uWHc@NwO6wSM0FskEoTf5W2LsQA8xcKocALZgPHQ2TI/Cr7@Aw8pWnABm3B@0@buWY8Ri1Y/DBaBTyHXmcUVwfOduXnBxV@iKm0AVwbmpLP8FqTVXIKxRlPXStSHM7gAOOqFu7XB1rjlg/foTggrvap4DOh6K0VRwglr3dtf3WY5MXKjukGtVXHTk3CnxrKuXE4aW8lCjFGcURBUfgGsS0t7eXI9Uw4soR/lXF7UV24wo@1h75phDOoA29E/quHP8JE9pg@8dfVFhFrZ4zH0RxK@BqNk7hdm6o04nns9IndLENtO43nLS0z8SMDrXClB5uKGBsk4bdjh01GJ5bpFYhr0uQhBLKGfF22o9xNjo0V1b5jLTfkjXYPx1pVG3XtSgivVkc0Rya@YhS1kwfyTKzIgZ0aAg2xiGytl/@UtNo217fSqzWXXBD/Nl2lUO6@dOTQ/Sl0OSL8psc7jB9wa4BMiySV/h9YfufL5vv1KOGns4OYzv3baP7rWLN17Cepaw01aSNkO3U4drScTE/82uDhALE5REz6Yp1koumBCBVGGGGS0EdmNpEHyWe9NkA81f5wsTkurLQSao@U4dhlSgbU3h7bmKtNfnL1IQoSD/RVWrPyOxjV9DsrIalr6LJqRL8TXXS1kQTvuiZeJ1dJ6dOSNM2RMawjdYJ1L6KtuM4B8ljQ8uREqV/CO2mtqrPSAhB9mJQ8phqFRyqjGG1rmhcZuWkBgzbtLSPk5kGEWE42FC5Ma19ArnQuBm4mGQcdZPmWtVrQFhOypGBW4221Bm9CkTo8D639nln6ymvb8lQzQwgHiw86KmRhUHJZmaLjKABWyPxjFhhsNCUGt7IcQ7Z1/TKhT9Oq8BddcdF58fdzyLrvLUtp3C4lUX/SidN/wjB2ALHXuILy/p8ktrdrbLQS2FFveDzxq4nvV8qX4A5szFAdV/NF/gRGFNIR@a3AtFaPV@6YoWTDx2Q/WdzyHi4m0cr21jGN7gD6OJqu/7oHSMUCFvuY6rfR2M76BSqGWw4989nOz8lh9yCZJWOIN37hroqidZw9o@CtHFWRfWKw6oFqri2woOqo@lp3mZ0kGRdUoPlQrP1Sd1GJB3doD3SouMnJIbFk1bl6NxOTYoTH7BSS5nbeZab9UozYiKQ@sy2L8aYx/x1xdBUh3h9a1Pjr22UJqjnVT5YcsaBfCYPvi/HdofJMuHTDe7xtMrJA6z4ao3lPG8yFV7Zabuvldhblf/ILOdpm5cvb8iUas8Sa@AFTgXGUjFs9BZSK@QdxO5HX934FN5NdljwDjbrtaMmGOc7VQl8BSue0crpkKFYLTb3g9/lpaO7gsoXQq0h2z6cAsiwt9qhbQcxSrst2wm@rcUfMAG2Z1sMHMihlZc/9UzrfGKrK@pjY@xQzdxQMMe/9@7TUtrbJiK/dHbNa6yFwaHYn3rbd/KQT8eiOLHc1OaonDrw/lgMTxaEwConLN0nQVXLIkrSPee0oYYe5NO/eUSD1G22beWxTXF8ud9bhl@idZmP/mwNZA58YIIqMg8U96jh3LNVBe8gYBmen5Gbdvx84o9pVjH2FLbIq/KCS/7wTZ/Mlkb9q8FE87Ii@yGlrqetLgGbr@35UYj4F1yh@hGMP88Yt3R@hKqtFcdYyflcD8FtWEKxYUWbISIl2k5U/jZ@Bn/u3HKPklL0h4BmftO/6lUMP5GaYW0Mrr@rXGzWZaieJS4xbmcaettSs8LKsxsSDq4Pgw/nzHr9tiW1UfZ3dbzD4/sspzVxHos30kP3Fje3Ef7zfQxBGli54OuLGWxvZNoyERU@pyXvhFnqrcY8pLkPhmetpLPxLa13jX0sOJx2dOyNWWlMZ0YK8qUWKRdh8roUbPsUNEvirkf9gT1PxzflxdeHr35YKLj8kcfPGJycenY9Ehwax0scr5/8euagJddUa8OZgSeXIxTCooHsm3WqIekSmKsbX5InS0OWIBvYodjSopFV@pdEUWXspTW9Jyb0ijjS6a10cWb8rNIh@xF@vXim7GSqkpDW7aTru7tmZo9ejIcNJpGi5io7iILqeyaAxJsXSJpu8WiTRi7f8TSNWRB0N4t7gyCc32m3hNe@PYkSWeqD4bkj/nllOTzYUs6u1e2NX10XO7k3CTzwnhigbwciYjpdH57IcdYDn8KpJ@5YZGroMrjxFiK8VouCNPHVPSjJHVIzNw/1Uh9cBnC4bynzHLokiylOjZ/d2GXow@NsrkTfvWw4bRP@ms0kIxU2adMxZ7XaZqpuD@c477splmyTjrGM3vKtYKnQ4e6cR1@U30UInQdLFtrDYLyjWGjukVltkqWHHFKGYe0Ixmf0sh6WEoojsnUTB6xDoCVkILrZcoWahEJU4U8j0V6vy/Cc8xz@Iv@7gRxDdQaHrGdyqP/T/@C@5fjQoULg1iGNQVoicyWqePrxXKj6lcy/lIA@JyVSOtzIt5dCsM1ubhMkfT7Puh7vmfnWPd0@VkDX0YX@WrQSkXd2lthe9DcPneS24R0kcyvpJ2w7R9o8iOauQCkZ8Lnqr6UOL9Rj822kUV5xz@dkHmkD9VSxGf17GT2XDwhc/36NMz5XvK1zfFZuNH7I3@YzsrBYPK@ps7pKYvG9t2M8LqY4fHYvDobLQw0xzqb@0FvwodRWAOI7ZYYYHgPEjUVvgOoXDVWfYW@Y9rxBd1WYYBwzf@/OyWZzWsJhz2EzPPLpuOu3ntFuA9GhzKuqiIWvi40vZ@dJqa7FFI@DqLzrQDOiRAc/6PMrz7mR51najWdYK9AbNdUMUPXAJWEK5FzQfcTRlrgdEOYndNe2mV0ypi6qyGlk0iVQyAJpMpTtP2kc4j8YdD8mqtPjEr8vDQNH5lvX7nKaGn7hwr814nGYWRt72RevxQHaXjlJfZbdwyVS3dqRVKJ/7fpj5DZ2wZhlQ556FiiREb1U7PchVPjn3ZZt@NLkzWCHtHs0cS9W5t@dKKEos5DXe1fjcVRbTPGYRsxJHdrwc1VNty4Si7KDY7KsAc20mj8BVQGLe/1yjLhx0Q/xL/xyaDtIzzTtAbR35Y5vD5BMkqRHlpXKc6gBz8sL2pXtADpDT3bDH9p3P0/5W163HIRvNdwDtObQ/IKhNNuPyw8XBkOrWlcif0tzICv6l1XooplUj8Tzk74yj330xsmnrP9OsIhTEyLYn0tswYL1sHAQtwALSXAx/WlalGHW8lmjNi5Ty2jm3F98EJok2Azd8Cosl1qe1W8dtiq@8Hnd4atIHPrWIEkX2V7bH8UDHsaWS@VXyINXfCj8Aphuvw6MPXsd6C0wAIqYQLAIvHtgydbjgTTp0cCW4Q0a00KvX40IF@WDT7jkBm8/MMiMArPPTUfGPFHqA3SxkbSybUBrdSgdUSKCfqOh5mbn7zoqY2l@AqKcOsXtlHzhFCQ5So9KnSoUagAqXGg5ApA9ChfPnZ2GHHfXOcbTvfbOv3Z2u3HtJDIs0ZojTT0o7JFbr8Rc6DILucZRLGuImK7sb/CIn9a3EVtC532bfRGtUUCgRsfAAsojnvPZZgtHh40/wSo7mJCjwygHJX5h0qpoayuCo7Kr6xdFhySW30TuHYsTyPSrqKitscRPHygiSoz@u5nYD2CmODDpZvh83wuj2sJVK3@J6vIa8UqUmAR9ZtD@D/1zY2w725gBYXA/uGFmJKdhSTqKCbLZ6B2Uj0kf0yGGiA3l7/@ZCNcRFLew6NMKObYcAauVLrRzE8yTOjBNb1vGv/oe@nqGGPdsj1T3SO09smGakG4y5s6oD2N/G@226NG/J/kYfeDEO4vgpuZYvnpPQ6Z8vs/1dgdCKLW8l8B7E2mzvXrQ6SmI4VDn@tozwQGObk9OB8HnbcR6T6IO5/hEG3SFR1c9OaarjyTLvJeMjj6KAneFhlg6cDwdDy5j@tIXpq6y3rdDKchxF3egxTmj8BSZdkc8eaWzszI0pPulS5BUqo6Sg3d2xMK0d76OPN@v0Gdz59/FdZhwcmM9O/JO0Fjot0s9o3ue@P2B@PDcAKuQpUNBCAMTmI23lOyo4rWdLZEPvufyJ49NZ7jrev/@CgFLD1JC2iO7BhZZiOptGMRyHQ0vDgSF7RhfD@wUfHcruMB40opwTVo5HMTTFYYtPlmVw0orJrd6IaVvlmd@gD/RXAqU6rjX2RP/aFrf4u2/j5JYYoZPqO5kDHfwKf82qLsiLLm22884n7Zh1k4@fuUUt2/GLHG4gMjbO5hzNY66jTfoes9xDZvOSe2EdvxEu4/3QvYN25gcT9bHh2IbG02aJmLIPFHDZoVm34XLUvLKimKZpSUz6EuBXuyVIVYLfwCxjDibp89SQoR@JyVpF2Y28Ixwxt2qRquxF17vz7RV1G59JhSaBUbhP61FTg0lP5p/ij4rymBoEc0Nes9OAcp0qLqJh62@hTxwPljXTfmJFZI6k1amLgJX6UpVeBcg@7pa0XwjekWs60I6pSzMWYtxxDwIzcAK4RLqiRWS9r9nC1yftVeBkt4KiUpU6zESPPww5aPlxBgxj3KrUfriy48xjCAK3ypuY3MVqP5PF70@leeQyyNMgIlYgZpYoScJPbiE18nFyT@Pdzx8@o8ZkeH5o@D2lFQv4MdA8Rayeg9x7eRq6Wup6jGSZyq5@KgeVx7FZQPWx/105L3Y0ZxSwlk@vkztH227RiLhq3KYSI1712N6/35eIGtuzo7u33r2XeXhLUUzvU2hTT7N/uT@hRsZxfLEUCxQCjXQcyybznxL7IrBOor0NkwW/ZivQEmnapYkl6nZ4qgXGKb17onleaYwEL7ovu0FjSMLTQ@hpMb3xVve@gnbxznZTo3Ef8vc0xiK0/rqs/jG2RRe034EjDYRwllxAWI//2k5o02BsnP@yKQli4mzMEvfOJzakTiDysEttg/qvodMFvri9FbdjXgNEVREA@KpeMDA1ejkPmTGE8CJu5tiucAFYsZ3dIN6we3fhMUNGWfA2u8loNr3zuhQ244tF/Fr5KSIHF1AxejPVUZNL9VnleM@wHUNznLFKpXbdbgTzlvMaah5WqGceuyLVSVhxbpEU3UCxMxfITm0yu/wz2rPgeYy@sR4NAnu9qe5FWvb5VdA0mrxEnFkAaOQlEek2RR@KbmJQUPpEzBgxUqNWNrBpw54s3z21W7G2pP37XTwJvyuT4U822mEqzQI/8R8tkPlU@mjh5Vk7eq/yYJHGFoscSzMf2mP6zNXoNOXwnT@mxvHka0D30BmqiBb1wfVewqOTtCNNKkq9//9K/XfhfyqthdAZrTrQmB/PLyz87/8B)

Comment: what is the `1` doing on here `(...)(1, j=0, ...)`

Comment: @ajax333221 This is the initial value of `n`, as an argument passed to `g`.

Comment: oh thats right hehe, sorry first time I see passing arguments on self invoked functions on arrow functions

Answer (score 3):

## C, 7525 bytes

Score: 207 (code) + 7316 (data file) + 1 (overhead for extra file) + 1 (name of the file)

```
char c[7316],b;int i,j,k;main(){fread(c,7316,1,fopen("a","r"));for(;k++<29903;){for(i=0;*c>=(b="M/2R"[i]);++i)*c-=b;putchar(48+i);j=*c%b;for(i=1;i<7316;i++) {j<<=8;j+=c[i];c[i-1]=j/b;j%=b;}}}
```

This assumes that char is unsigned, non-Windows system, and writes 0123 instead of ACGU. Add "unsigned" replace "r" by "rb" and use "ACGU"[i] to make it portable and understandable.

It requires a data-file "a" in the same directory, which hex-dumped is:

```
45 3b 74 a6 ef 77 b7 75 2e c4 e0 6d 77 10 28 da 
ba b4 1c 54 bf 6c f5 a6 66 b3 e6 42 77 15 60 3c 
e3 5e f0 57 67 5a 3e 14 87 64 98 6d 4a fe 88 8b 
b0 5f 90 1e af 32 a2 57 1f 60 bc bf 9b 77 0f 56 
ba 58 22 a7 e5 b3 45 9a 09 a0 a6 de 2e 77 f7 90 
23 a9 f5 c8 f3 f9 06 de 5d 17 dd e4 e9 19 39 0d 
45 7a c5 1f ed 77 2b 9b 1e 59 25 6a 58 41 08 6f 
a4 70 65 41 61 fe bc 10 e0 6c 8a a0 dd 5f 8d 63 
22 1c 13 df b6 49 1a b5 eb 7c ae f3 2f 23 03 1a 
19 71 2e 64 ab e0 02 45 ae 79 dc 2f 08 8e f1 08 
76 09 1f 01 57 1c 7b a4 3c 97 35 f1 1f 93 0f 76 
c5 0b 6c 6c 96 b7 2b e3 79 0f b8 e0 08 8a ae 8d 
5f 0a 59 d3 ba eb 50 d2 40 9c 64 1b 18 92 93 cf 
96 1b bc ba d2 9b c9 88 0e 1b f3 86 4d 2b 8b b8 
fb b6 2d 95 87 53 27 7a f0 ac 2d 6b 83 5c c3 6f 
ca 64 59 df 71 9f 40 88 2d 3f e6 12 7e 18 f4 6a 
60 9b 09 3d e8 ee cc 3d b7 40 ea 52 35 27 f2 21 
d5 18 62 05 f2 13 56 1f 9c 59 e8 de ee 99 db 85 
9e 25 6b de 72 c6 56 78 bb 13 76 8b f4 c0 45 54 
bd 7c 42 83 25 c9 5f c0 b4 b2 29 5e c5 c0 80 76 
80 21 f4 f3 95 c5 e9 b6 ed 9c 25 52 9c 6f 4e 8a 
d8 56 23 6c db a3 83 cf d7 e6 4f d4 77 9f e3 49 
fd 0c 41 ef 42 df 08 bd 94 77 c2 60 06 d7 99 db 
55 a1 ea 4a 23 4b 4e ed 9d b8 4c 1f 0f cf d7 82 
19 19 76 cf b7 60 a7 ae 08 46 c0 75 78 3f 3b 3d 
73 34 b9 fb 9a 75 27 f2 5b 11 88 3b 03 6d e8 b1 
df 1c 94 5e 09 06 d2 54 6b fe 87 d5 48 d5 41 e9 
43 5a 02 02 5d 7b e5 30 fe 3a f3 d9 b6 26 db 9e 
b1 50 af e9 cf 96 eb 7e ae c5 ec 3b 19 cc cb a8 
e4 fd b9 6c 0f 74 f0 c8 49 3c ac ba d9 4d 9d e0 
64 0c 17 a6 54 cb 16 5c 31 55 eb 49 e4 a9 d8 d3 
f4 44 b8 e4 9d 4c b2 3a 5b 26 2c 59 11 28 2b a6 
1c b3 6e 51 91 d6 63 d8 11 46 de 66 9e 12 2f 96 
af a6 29 49 66 91 ef a7 de d9 3f a5 b6 83 c1 1e 
e0 fa 98 76 1c b9 c8 2d e7 60 15 b7 77 a3 7a 09 
bb ae 81 ee c7 93 d1 25 a4 3a 39 0d 20 ee 86 c5 
4c c2 f3 cf a9 70 00 92 fa a0 09 33 a6 0f 5b 13 
73 44 03 2f 8c 98 56 84 3b 30 17 4f ac f1 c9 13 
40 61 89 39 17 3c 38 86 9f 22 ab 50 bb a2 40 03 
44 14 ce c3 6d 42 6f 7c 91 af c8 00 45 24 bd 1f 
a1 9c 93 39 4f 52 ed 3b 3c 77 39 17 ed eb c8 99 
cd 36 e9 67 cd 11 e5 f6 57 e6 c0 9e 8f 7d a7 a7 
ea 21 f1 1e dd 2f 22 ab 93 95 c9 03 2e b4 3a 26 
a1 26 82 32 40 a3 82 bb b9 55 5e 3d 16 02 c7 4c 
5f ed 22 94 a8 b4 ba e1 7c 87 43 ab 72 ba 26 5e 
2d 81 71 d1 2d db 0e b5 ea 6c a1 ac 53 95 8e e7 
8b 52 ff ab 1e 7e 80 7a 79 ce 2c a4 be 85 ad b5 
a3 6b 07 7c 67 d5 c6 00 b1 5b 08 79 ff 6c 14 fc 
04 7d 5a a6 22 51 1e 24 ce cc 59 cb 68 24 fd 53 
40 bb dc e0 9f 18 3c 6a ff ca 6b bd e5 c0 c5 e9 
ff a2 5a 56 7c 05 d9 11 6b bd 34 1f bf 56 27 75 
1b 12 01 00 e6 76 b1 30 16 b5 0d fd fd d8 29 52 
31 ba 66 23 8c f0 f2 e8 f1 0e 55 7f ee fd 43 1a 
61 ad 87 b2 cd b3 b3 4b 3a c8 2e fa 92 a6 a6 cb 
60 c2 11 28 b4 5a 72 a2 7d f4 e3 82 1a e3 2b 91 
6e 46 8d 4d be 6d 65 bc 88 85 43 16 a0 59 d2 b8 
38 db 84 dd 77 1f e2 d1 97 1d 80 3b 23 ce d4 d4 
51 58 bc 06 30 f2 6f 0c fe 0d ff 86 26 71 0e 89 
c6 ab ab 0d a1 97 0a 1c 4c 89 19 61 b7 ca 25 40 
2b c0 3c 8d 41 38 b4 a5 56 47 e5 ee 97 d4 43 6c 
74 d7 78 55 00 5d 07 df c7 32 45 88 c7 34 54 69 
a5 31 35 5d 40 81 1e 98 86 af 27 ca c5 22 da dc 
37 78 52 4f 37 3c 13 d5 45 43 1f 83 91 5a cb 7b 
b1 9c ea ba 60 69 f9 35 30 44 5e 1f 8d d8 73 1e 
ec 06 42 87 53 bc 52 66 12 19 66 b0 56 2c a2 47 
27 2e 41 ac ee a6 52 5f 24 30 5d af 5e 6b b6 d5 
70 a8 80 f0 a2 83 3b e3 c6 ef 59 29 d1 85 bb a8 
fe 23 93 35 d1 c1 c9 37 f4 3f 39 fd 9b 39 60 ab 
6b 73 af a7 6d bc a0 d7 b3 5d 97 ef 89 30 23 19 
ef 45 76 ec 42 72 36 24 eb 33 aa 21 ec 1f 52 ed 
ad 1f bf 7c 63 16 e6 60 fd 15 d6 fa df 68 15 90 
41 73 fd d1 6c 89 30 49 48 be ea 93 54 39 08 85 
f7 57 8f 76 b4 42 e6 2b 1d 8d d3 96 2b 7b 5f 57 
16 9c 48 6e 89 85 50 4b 23 72 b7 5b cc ff 40 53 
4f 83 ad ba d0 87 fd 5d 41 96 0f 1a e4 a7 49 69 
d5 24 2a ce 3f c2 0c 6a bd 3e 4b 7d b5 ca 8e b5 
ac ac 4b 12 cf d2 32 b2 d8 15 82 62 bb 3c 48 50 
a6 65 02 8f 22 88 36 0b 32 2b 9f 7c 0e 31 08 40 
10 66 76 35 ef e0 1c e5 ef 31 1b bd fa cc 52 f0 
a5 d5 60 51 ad ea b3 17 e0 12 56 95 ac 37 9c 5b 
24 ba 8d 1a 3b 81 2f 55 5a af d9 2e 7b 5b 5e 53 
80 b4 3a cc e6 ec 88 ed fd a4 00 1e c9 8b 06 1c 
bb 64 68 1a 97 20 60 ad 22 07 71 d1 55 da ae e0 
41 c1 85 ea 4f 32 0e 97 ee ca 78 93 92 c5 86 bb 
6e 77 cc d8 5b fb 29 36 21 fc 77 2f ef d0 1d c9 
ab f6 02 72 a6 a3 33 ee 13 27 d5 c2 6b 2e 34 88 
a8 b9 0e 59 b9 60 b8 e2 a3 ad b3 28 10 f0 3d 0e 
42 30 e7 d5 5a 80 20 ea 1c 9b b0 25 31 78 52 b8 
cc 63 91 55 d9 bd e4 8e c5 bb 1a a3 d8 5d 3f 78 
63 d3 cf 80 c4 85 fc e3 41 db aa b0 0e a3 82 b7 
a4 70 c2 c6 c1 58 59 e8 49 e4 4e 62 95 38 3d c4 
6c f4 1a 1c 00 d5 c1 fb 8a c5 d2 03 12 60 97 a6 
bd 12 49 f5 bc 74 b0 5f 9b 6a 52 e9 59 2d 9e 60 
bd b3 2e c5 9f 4f d1 8d 90 21 77 5e 49 af 66 d6 
66 39 d9 16 2c ce 83 ef e0 4f 1e c6 59 02 8a 5e 
d2 00 87 76 9f cd a1 da a5 e6 2d 25 a2 02 0c 58 
e2 8e 8f c8 5a 94 e7 a6 fe d6 1e a4 ef 3b f5 3a 
2a 33 e7 e8 8f 48 26 39 bb 81 5d 6e c5 5e 56 99 
a6 7d 08 db d6 14 c3 10 6a 33 d6 b4 96 44 5c df 
6b 3d dd dd 5e 3f 5c 66 29 d4 a0 d6 b7 67 96 1d 
b3 5d 68 ff 22 19 ae b3 04 45 cb c3 fa fd 77 bb 
c4 ec 50 dc 79 df 7f 7d b0 d4 6c 3f b8 ae 95 17 
ac 51 12 49 69 4f 13 17 24 a5 8e 13 fd 28 44 00 
7e 11 88 a0 ad 41 ad ae e3 6a a5 61 09 0d 2f da 
16 0e 21 f8 a3 00 8b 55 f0 88 ef b4 70 82 d3 d9 
1a 02 22 66 28 a3 ad 45 cd 1b b3 fb 3b 85 03 a6 
49 69 fd af 9c 10 ad e7 d9 36 83 c2 7b d2 b3 1e 
7c a7 7a e5 17 14 af 1f 2c 2f cb 3d c8 67 cd bd 
08 b9 c4 f0 41 fc bc 6f 28 32 5e 51 4a 5e 5c 82 
53 14 15 ac f5 5f ff 6f eb 80 85 17 5b 2b ea 7c 
b4 7c ac c5 05 c6 8b 79 96 bc 68 b9 99 29 69 90 
98 ff 3d 07 9c 4a 11 f9 20 97 60 55 b6 6a 6b 95 
07 98 37 47 c9 53 45 a0 b6 8e 3b 3f bc c7 6f 73 
4a 1c 88 7a ab 93 ef a8 f6 7b e3 bd 74 f7 55 d3 
1e f2 fa 2b 72 92 08 d8 2b 05 97 b2 6e 55 ab 39 
58 f2 f9 36 c0 42 f1 aa e6 c3 85 9c 03 c8 02 95 
04 ae 40 12 d6 da 02 60 5d bc 7a c3 d7 c1 67 17 
42 df 3e 13 9c dc b1 17 dd da d5 91 61 0d cf 8e 
ab 8e 9c 93 fa a8 b9 7b c3 00 75 82 cd 30 a1 8d 
cf 5b 0d a0 e6 13 dd 32 35 4d 45 95 ac 67 5c d7 
42 44 de 9b 9c 7e f9 d6 4b 3d 1c 7e 67 c2 fd d8 
3b 1a cb 63 4e d7 0d 9a 40 1a 45 1c f3 70 a4 64 
6e 67 15 0b 61 cb 43 82 95 ff cf 1f 34 36 e5 3e 
ec df cb 5d 79 02 96 38 74 7f 4e db 0e 95 76 94 
12 d7 61 fd d0 37 6a df 8d fa e5 38 15 19 a7 73 
e8 1a 50 78 8f c5 e4 2c ab aa e7 01 ef 5f 01 ca 
db d1 c8 19 3d 1a 20 02 19 90 bf 26 96 bb a8 91 
a1 63 81 89 44 d0 34 53 b4 cb 4b 86 02 5e 2d 69 
f7 d1 b9 f1 3c 4c 69 6f 8a 94 9b 1c 4e f7 74 fe 
ba fa 1b 43 50 af ec bd 15 cf 2c 7a bc 40 e9 6a 
b8 4e 05 e3 42 cb 08 f8 5f f0 a2 42 e6 da d3 c9 
42 4f ce 92 ae bf 19 54 6c 15 ff 41 9b 08 d9 6f 
08 38 09 8b 4a fd c7 de 66 cf f1 2c 0f ed 57 57 
46 73 87 4a bb bc d3 ba 24 c1 b8 c9 49 69 3a a4 
32 3f 3d ae 22 ec 47 6c f5 9c da 1b 31 74 47 e4 
b9 e2 14 db a7 89 8a 05 74 e7 04 79 d4 83 a1 20 
9f 15 50 6d 6b 26 3d b5 d2 3b 1c 14 1e 4a 5a ad 
e7 8e ef ed dc 33 c2 86 1e 7f 16 c9 1f f5 a2 88 
1e e0 d5 53 42 37 f7 71 70 43 4e b6 56 42 30 3c 
48 61 e8 87 75 34 ea 15 6c cd 7d fc 63 0c 4a 89 
62 57 ce cc d4 cd d4 41 51 45 c3 e9 8f 21 20 95 
f0 c9 fe c8 04 1f c6 41 a1 cd 96 d6 a7 d1 ba 2a 
2b 80 a4 aa e0 c3 4a b2 d8 ba 0d ec b7 78 a8 76 
be 6d 48 34 a4 75 c1 c9 b2 f2 56 43 e9 4f 03 bb 
31 7d 21 8d a1 e1 da 94 0b c4 6b 57 b9 e3 f2 2f 
9f 29 ec 8f 36 8b 60 e1 69 73 b1 84 7b 02 8e 2d 
e5 b7 0c 93 2f ee 04 e8 52 26 66 92 f3 ed 31 cd 
e9 fd 54 06 d5 c1 7e b4 15 7e 13 18 b8 75 a9 3d 
e2 68 bd fe 77 36 ce 81 20 b0 45 b3 ea 18 5b 18 
12 08 15 53 67 e5 94 fe 10 cf 86 7a 85 c4 39 dd 
23 5d 29 81 23 cb e3 49 4c 65 6b 00 6b 40 87 24 
08 49 ea 02 81 c3 86 54 41 40 d8 9d 1d e0 19 4c 
f9 79 29 74 96 cf 25 4b c0 b1 09 45 4f 94 e0 c1 
47 5e 95 7a bd 5f 02 05 3e 97 30 eb 4b d8 a3 84 
f5 8e ca 9a 6f 50 5a 25 71 ee d8 5f bd 01 1f ef 
af fd 39 af e3 e2 21 29 f8 f6 5c 46 57 a9 e9 3b 
1e 01 34 28 a9 08 99 8e 87 07 54 c2 4a da 59 7e 
e4 54 a7 95 0b 79 75 13 fa ce cd d3 17 bd 2d a9 
74 fe 7c 22 9d 47 8d 67 c0 6e d3 7e cd 6b 26 4a 
1e eb 05 b7 e8 80 a6 46 38 eb 51 1c 36 a1 b3 cb 
4f 4a bf 9d cf cd 8c c5 38 8e 9f a5 3a ee ef 0c 
f6 67 c2 15 d6 f3 e0 2a 83 ee e9 34 b3 bd 1a 76 
ec cd 7c f0 c2 43 0c 46 b3 47 d0 84 d2 f9 f1 67 
f0 f1 e6 2e 07 08 d9 5e 83 90 dc b1 be bc 1e 9f 
47 5f fb f0 52 ff 58 c8 fe 45 9c 7f d8 98 e1 05 
36 cd bd 06 3a 4f 79 55 0e 04 86 ee 0a 03 cb cb 
f5 2e 1c 78 09 a7 da 2c c0 51 a4 79 d2 5e a6 81 
fd ec da 27 93 50 4b 6e f9 93 2f b6 37 cd c6 45 
f3 4e fb f7 17 bc 15 b1 d7 5a bc f2 80 42 05 3d 
12 e5 2d 7c 93 b8 11 9d ab 1a ea 46 14 9e 07 67 
9a bb 4c a7 cc e7 51 f5 86 1f 3e 7d 86 ce c2 54 
84 f8 f9 0f fb 28 18 f3 18 a3 0c 53 61 77 a9 5e 
b2 ff 97 2d 1c 18 7c f0 ef f7 70 c4 5e 19 bb f6 
8e 68 e0 15 46 e0 1c 83 01 c7 ee 7b ac 86 28 7d 
51 f5 d0 f6 fc 2f 09 b6 11 3a 08 04 8c 44 98 cd 
0c 2c 57 08 a6 96 76 02 58 02 5e e8 8f 24 84 7f 
17 8a 1d 36 db 9e 84 74 37 c5 5f 42 08 d6 b2 ca 
eb ed 75 31 6a 14 19 ed c3 ba ed 5d 6e 98 bf 6d 
9d f3 0f 00 fb 54 bf 5c 79 75 08 2a 22 c2 9c 77 
dc d6 a0 13 3c ff 51 92 e5 c2 99 f5 46 43 7e f6 
1e aa 7b 53 35 10 8e 9a e3 12 e6 97 45 05 cd 03 
8d ec 23 fe cf bf d1 0b 1e 39 fd 0e 2f 69 2c 97 
5f 4d 43 04 7d d4 98 0f 5d 66 49 6d 3a e6 a6 24 
bc 1f 7d f5 23 27 ca b9 81 28 7f 91 b9 8a 9b 77 
c7 7a e9 7d f6 25 04 9a e1 8d 16 0e a7 7f cc be 
06 28 eb 98 a0 59 19 db b4 b4 77 5d 30 f7 15 4f 
65 b5 61 37 05 0a 80 8d d5 bd 39 3d 25 a3 72 dc 
1d 30 e7 f6 47 a0 14 aa f1 d6 3e 20 f8 51 ec b9 
08 57 81 52 0f 54 4e cb 9d 20 4c a6 64 a6 8a 37 
2d 00 09 28 4d 9c e9 24 1f 7d 74 66 66 ab 92 ff 
23 05 04 3b fd 12 17 b0 23 c8 ae ef 17 25 81 d0 
fd b5 ef bc 43 6e 83 35 cf 65 82 28 93 0a 69 52 
4a f7 79 be 7e 7c 44 58 91 ec 3e f3 49 51 fe 6c 
05 e7 92 d2 6a 30 76 ab 7e e7 8d 94 96 73 98 bb 
be 95 bc 6b cc 87 ae 6c 29 67 c5 c7 3e cb 57 f0 
cd 01 b4 33 26 e3 7a 55 50 99 9f 8e c7 88 04 cd 
14 61 90 8d 12 c6 94 cd 1e db 93 3c a9 da c7 a8 
ee 3f 3e 3c 5a c0 00 9e d4 0f 8a 88 4d 99 9f 84 
1c 91 9c 20 4d dc 46 98 95 dd d8 b3 ca 0a 98 3b 
34 65 12 a7 55 7d 4b 4d 3c a9 54 df 68 9d c6 f4 
3d b5 a1 54 cb d8 d2 3b 7b e1 ce 7f ad c0 78 1a 
af d2 66 80 58 e3 d8 4e dd 3a 3a 87 f1 21 0c c9 
f4 8c 20 d1 0a 53 38 1e 7b 58 20 df 0b 97 48 f4 
e4 c7 87 b5 1f 51 7a b2 03 f5 eb 50 d5 ba 81 38 
53 54 70 a8 07 36 b0 d5 c0 c7 d7 61 f9 6d 4f ae 
7a c5 15 ee 8e 07 af 8d d9 a9 62 a1 c1 b1 28 31 
10 51 fe 54 69 42 ae d6 e1 82 bc 16 b9 f8 95 4a 
1f 66 27 6f da 2b fe 23 7f f5 6c c8 89 c2 d3 5f 
ad 95 23 09 c3 63 b5 f5 3b 28 d8 85 dd 4f a5 57 
12 5d 63 41 b8 2b 6c a4 96 a1 48 e9 1e 19 06 62 
9f 22 4c 14 9f 64 58 41 3e 2b 76 9d 2e 4c cf e1 
12 ea 89 8f f5 0c 76 95 98 82 2f 62 e7 1a 47 90 
70 6c 0f 92 87 54 c1 24 3c d8 7e 8a 5e da 59 20 
fd 38 51 ed 73 bd 8e 68 53 e5 d9 88 b4 e3 46 00 
5e 3c 91 8a 3c c0 d1 d6 b7 13 5d f4 66 2e 38 ca 
94 d2 c7 d9 04 54 18 5c b3 23 fc cd 8b 2a 2e f1 
5d e8 30 e8 28 a0 f9 73 4a 73 7a ff 7d dd bc fb 
55 e2 38 09 1c c6 5c b6 a6 f1 cf fc b8 c5 79 bf 
06 9d b2 97 8c a3 bf db ef fe 4a 96 74 31 4f c9 
a8 4b ea 2d d8 fe d0 0c cc 36 b0 ea 6f aa d0 2c 
14 81 d6 1d 70 ac 7e b9 87 92 8f 24 34 4a df ea 
98 54 55 65 08 95 84 ee 0b cf af c7 56 5f 29 27 
54 51 00 7c 1f b7 c7 36 de d4 81 fa 69 07 ba 4b 
6a 08 66 38 c4 8b 05 e9 ec 18 df d6 4b 52 0d e2 
a4 a5 bb 23 1d 6e 06 86 e2 60 5c 05 5f c6 f1 4d 
3f a5 d7 a3 b6 9a 07 62 ca 81 74 e9 6d 15 e2 9b 
32 bc 78 79 2f 34 31 62 12 12 8d 10 3a 23 a6 2d 
53 34 0d d4 95 d0 f7 76 65 45 b2 6d 3b 07 df df 
95 37 eb 64 21 33 b2 25 c6 77 01 38 ba 73 ef 1b 
b9 56 3e 25 bf cc 95 e8 e8 52 ef f4 9d c5 a0 4a 
8c ff c9 34 65 36 c1 e3 fd a0 00 43 dd 5b 54 71 
e6 f1 f5 f3 2d 7d 26 aa 94 2f 06 3c 5c 10 32 7d 
13 07 6a 03 49 77 27 c8 fa 72 54 6a f8 a4 65 33 
cf f3 02 b8 2d 6b e0 1d 99 8a 55 e2 20 1a 10 6f 
ee c3 5b 6c 5a 04 b3 b5 f5 eb 8d 36 1d c0 44 7b 
63 ac 29 39 9e 9f 14 f6 19 45 4f cd e5 00 8e bf 
f7 49 c1 31 44 fb 46 be 10 a0 89 98 7b 0e 60 90 
1b 28 26 76 33 d4 31 f9 c7 d7 d3 15 ad ff cb 41 
8c fc de 5f 3c f8 5a 8c 8c 7a 87 13 03 eb d5 50 
a3 a9 be 8b 70 6b 1d d4 20 12 2a fd 23 26 e2 3e 
82 a2 a3 47 bc f6 36 28 1b 42 ae a6 ab f6 34 8d 
10 96 3f c8 a8 c0 60 58 5b 40 f8 96 00 27 fa ef 
22 05 28 b7 aa 5d ae d2 10 d6 b1 17 7c 17 1f f0 
e2 5f 86 07 41 b0 46 d7 76 21 00 7b 0b 9e 0d b5 
2a a9 dd 08 4e d2 72 13 d5 60 ce b5 fe a7 9a 08 
93 09 94 e8 cf 94 c2 99 81 ed 34 1d b9 0e 2d ec 
cc 42 41 7f 22 f4 69 2f 9b 59 76 6a b8 aa 31 d3 
40 96 8d ce 0c 9a d5 0a 5d 9e 58 be eb f9 7b db 
3e e2 1c fe 40 2a 37 48 84 c8 2f da 99 0b d8 52 
a5 1f e8 c7 ee 45 89 4f b7 6b 71 c1 f1 53 68 b0 
2b b0 29 d5 4f 95 91 a6 d4 db 20 72 ef 84 8e c1 
36 06 81 73 2e 2f 72 bc 82 3c 10 6b 3f 33 eb ef 
ef ad 28 fa c9 ee 59 a6 9a 91 cb e3 b1 b6 f6 b0 
db a8 4f 84 72 5c 5e 4e 88 0f 33 c7 57 c2 f2 03 
fc 94 fc fc 3a 9b 32 f6 8d 16 d2 bf c9 11 b9 91 
f7 43 38 1a 86 f1 34 cd 28 ae 4f 6d 18 57 21 3d 
59 d3 72 40 5f 42 46 b1 35 b8 04 1b 3e bd 3b 2c 
7c 8d 34 8a bd d2 b8 f4 8b f1 e5 01 98 1c 44 4d 
3f 7d a3 18 9f 40 41 90 c6 52 c4 44 b2 32 02 ad 
36 96 bc 7e 7c 01 f7 8d 91 93 1f 8d 6e 84 87 de 
d8 12 c6 b2 d7 73 a3 6f 25 63 34 d1 f7 62 a1 43 
a0 4e 00 9e a6 46 c7 7b 11 44 9f bc e2 42 b2 2d 
03 fe 80 c0 07 e9 ad f8 b1 d2 2b 54 3d ff ce 95 
74 f9 db 52 df 86 c4 85 4f 85 c0 6f 0b 49 29 6e 
b2 26 8a 1c bc 48 3d bd 33 40 54 55 2b a6 8d 87 
88 05 bc 8d 2b 07 d0 7c 09 bb 47 68 6f 7a c1 29 
2d 95 09 52 b0 ef a8 15 1f cb 7c f5 dd a4 e9 b7 
d8 51 ec 94 58 67 3c f1 e0 61 01 0e e4 42 47 a9 
ee f2 e0 1d ff d5 0a 50 30 19 ac 2d b5 6e 92 8e 
73 c7 0d 9a 09 86 41 32 b0 ac 01 64 1c ec 17 cd 
73 9f 18 1b 32 07 f8 75 2c 66 7c 3c 14 18 5e 4f 
12 35 5f f2 51 d3 62 28 c5 b7 93 0c 15 c1 88 68 
e2 83 aa 58 4a d3 76 8b a7 ae 9d 20 5c 6f f5 2e 
91 90 e0 48 be bf 58 75 c9 41 46 d9 1c d2 73 aa 
97 b0 10 ca 57 34 d5 68 48 cc 6f 41 02 22 26 e6 
58 a7 6c 7c eb e1 24 7e ab 1d 22 f1 dc 46 27 47 
8e 2d 86 1a 4e 2b 74 f4 db 0e f6 4f e5 92 56 cc 
f3 83 58 be 91 a3 7d 63 ae 91 02 c1 55 a3 d0 80 
de fc f3 b1 77 51 17 e0 5a 78 09 74 7b 18 b6 22 
18 d9 cb 4b 71 4c 4d 6c 07 b2 78 cc c9 90 d1 00 
59 cd 21 c8 90 37 51 ea 78 5c 2f 6b dc 3a 2a d2 
c4 eb db 32 02 eb 53 97 26 49 8f eb 63 e9 ed 16 
61 8f 5e 14 26 d3 d5 a1 c6 6f 96 14 8d 6e 41 db 
56 4f 9e ec 8a 8c 49 cf 24 e7 65 ce 69 53 07 37 
34 50 b0 23 f2 e2 ad db ee 83 87 b4 8f e5 c2 94 
2b 3d 3f 82 3e e5 05 cd 00 a6 5b bd 57 e3 71 00 
f3 33 a6 a5 e7 2b 82 1d 45 e9 6d 73 cc 11 c3 13 
33 86 b6 25 1a 77 2b 0e 63 26 ae ff 18 a9 02 e7 
e8 f7 6a fc 2c f0 a3 f9 65 c2 4c e7 b9 af 5f b4 
16 f5 b8 ec 68 db 1c b4 9b 67 0c 1a ed 35 9f cc 
c0 57 0c 8f da e1 09 c1 b5 ac 9d 6c 58 0d a5 82 
2e 07 45 24 30 30 16 ee 25 b7 7c 93 f5 9e f7 ac 
ed 6e 20 ec e4 5a c3 37 cd b9 a1 74 45 e5 9e 89 
17 ab 8b fe 30 b4 64 3f 1a 85 07 bd 8a a5 75 f6 
b5 91 97 c3 b8 0a 5b f8 73 55 3c 4a 29 14 66 db 
c2 77 de 01 f1 5a 89 6a b4 8c 0a c2 bf 21 02 0b 
65 a7 1a 46 2e 11 3c 5d 82 90 0b 46 e7 47 d2 a5 
a3 37 47 8d bb 07 94 36 37 5a 25 5a 22 56 c9 34 
c8 27 a9 75 7f 61 5a b6 1b 85 8d 8e cb 9f d8 e3 
8c 89 dd d1 c0 91 c1 b3 5d 87 c0 10 65 b2 10 68 
57 8a 63 6f 6a 21 41 63 95 71 1e 98 47 1c f8 a7 
5d 6e 9f bc e4 5e fc 36 2c a6 5c 9c 16 bb b0 8f 
8b 37 09 a0 07 e5 14 86 24 f5 eb 61 a3 a7 ca cf 
ca dc 79 b1 b8 05 c7 f2 eb 7b 2d 3b 1e 2b 88 10 
12 b5 b4 cb 38 0c 6f ac 36 09 74 ca ef ed 8d 05 
11 98 d1 94 18 3e c6 37 4c 72 f9 56 6f b3 2d e6 
4e 8d bb e9 ba 74 64 16 56 e5 90 bf 3c 3b f8 c2 
2b f6 36 01 2c 35 0f 74 57 e3 94 dd 5b a8 b4 11 
c4 70 91 6c 83 67 71 63 eb 1c c6 90 a9 c8 ce 8e 
08 d1 f2 51 62 dd 02 9f d1 de 69 0e 18 da 35 54 
ec 0a 03 2e 25 b6 0f 4f a0 f2 7a 7f 8c b1 f1 3f 
fb 13 ab 82 b1 4e ed 31 aa 04 88 22 b6 6e ef 5c 
40 a5 f0 54 f3 01 d1 07 b3 3e 70 ae f3 bd e2 ef 
43 94 99 27 60 9d b2 bb 4a 54 e9 c1 a9 ef 5c 51 
7d 6b 05 85 61 9c c3 09 db 7d da 7c b9 d0 c8 2a 
4f d3 91 00 57 17 87 fc fa 40 31 2a b9 9f 98 b4 
ba 8a 6f dd 62 a9 e3 a3 90 d7 34 b0 cb f7 fa e6 
7d d3 f0 6c 7b 13 b9 60 dd e2 83 fb 23 18 0d e5 
b4 56 8d f6 e0 cd a8 a4 ed ba 6b b3 92 c5 62 dc 
a2 59 6f 05 ae 8f 4e 84 2b 37 95 5a 10 0c f6 1a 
73 76 22 f6 d6 fd a9 5f ec 54 ef 0f bb 57 36 d3 
b8 46 ca f0 9e 4c 5a a5 1c ea 6e 50 75 b4 65 89 
e8 80 85 d4 d9 ed 44 5d 43 03 4d f6 c6 da f5 71 
90 49 46 5a c9 23 cb b1 66 d6 10 9d 74 94 2d 52 
35 c1 36 21 6e 0a ea 6d 25 85 66 42 dd 93 f4 bd 
34 4c ea 1b 1e 2c 52 6e 1f fb 5d 2e 83 d2 95 26 
71 3f 9a 03 14 ad 15 61 ca 44 fa 7c 17 e9 42 b7 
95 32 3e 3f fc 54 0a 1f 50 14 90 c8 1a 78 17 bd 
73 78 b9 e3 36 9c 03 12 0f 6e db 7d 9a 9d 1c 0e 
e8 46 0a 82 99 71 c3 43 49 1a 1c 66 5b 6e 49 fc 
01 e2 47 15 18 c6 60 8d b8 c7 50 21 75 fe 9a 11 
dc e2 de 19 ff 5e 63 b1 48 fa f2 27 06 c9 3d 9a 
a5 09 9a e7 c9 63 08 5d dd 05 c3 42 ef f5 65 b7 
c7 81 f0 d4 bb 6d 5a 6e b5 fc ba f4 e1 0d 99 d1 
f9 80 74 79 5c 2d 77 18 2d 71 4d 25 99 1b dc 7e 
0a b8 51 b1 42 e6 ab bd 05 26 31 7c 8a 08 a9 2a 
e3 a9 4b a0 3b 51 a6 0f df b2 9c 77 2c f2 21 de 
8a e6 a2 c7 aa ad 97 64 bf 8c 43 73 bd bc 16 0c 
a4 9a 99 1a a3 b4 bd 5c 21 d5 fe 60 ac 47 ba 52 
0b cd 5e ae 9a e8 57 27 59 e7 2a 41 07 28 26 c2 
cc a9 8f 75 1c 34 ab e0 00 4d b7 3a fb f0 3d c9 
b3 b3 cc ea 78 6d 2f e1 4c 77 61 70 1e 8a f3 39 
f9 b0 47 99 f8 31 6a 61 1b fe aa d3 b3 63 2d 96 
be 85 2f 6a 11 8d 45 c0 5f bd ba ba 97 05 83 af 
d0 46 35 6b 4d 1e fb 5d 47 ef c3 bc 17 70 e3 60 
bc 78 a3 96 16 4f eb 65 5d 43 3b 87 f3 e2 76 fd 
8c e6 a5 23 6a d1 59 67 d5 c5 dc 5d f0 3f 8d b7 
15 53 7f bd e9 53 35 8a 83 fb b5 31 62 d2 48 32 
0b 72 e5 0c 0e 11 cb f0 75 ed be 50 9a a7 34 52 
5d 55 5c 00 98 55 cd 63 89 a9 52 42 e0 18 b0 d7 
52 55 be 05 31 98 90 7c 01 33 5b ed 97 92 3f b5 
da 35 8d 4e 12 de b2 72 f3 6c cf 83 e8 ec 69 97 
d5 4e 9e b0 9a 5d 26 db 9a a5 bf fe 02 2d ac a3 
5b b1 3c 8f 3b b1 46 23 5d dc be d8 94 dd 49 b9 
57 6c a2 51 c8 94 c3 2e 2d 46 31 e9 8c 6e 84 a3 
e7 36 01 fc 17 8a 08 4d e8 fa 5e 06 2d 82 34 93 
05 33 39 9b 02 d2 e2 50 40 cc 5f 04 1c 00 64 78 
78 b6 87 5a d0 21 c7 b8 ee ad 99 a1 32 05 ac 9c 
bf a3 6a b8 f7 e5 a3 c0 36 25 16 69 34 4a 77 ac 
5b c6 5f 3f e8 2d d0 bd 81 11 a3 59 a2 b5 e2 ce 
63 dd 71 af 40 08 5d f3 77 a2 07 f3 2a e4 30 19 
e7 3c db ae a6 09 11 b2 48 97 1d 64 48 73 dc ce 
cc 6c 01 9a d6 8d d7 a7 95 2a 19 20 db 92 97 02 
34 15 f8 ce 84 8c 28 a0 3f 15 30 9c 80 8c b3 33 
23 d6 fc f0 61 05 94 41 a7 53 71 4a 82 1f 43 82 
d2 6d 75 c6 f1 7c b0 c1 a2 49 b1 2e b9 35 85 7d 
9f fe 21 d4 66 55 e3 7a dc 76 81 4c d9 6c f0 5f 
85 b3 bf 26 de 5f 61 9a 5c 13 77 ae 1f 62 b8 c5 
e2 9c 64 02 97 2e 7d 86 b6 3f 0a a9 e5 2a 95 41 
ff 26 18 00 60 46 d7 b3 9a 19 e2 66 31 8a 76 f8 
ac b2 e3 1a 44 73 8b 0d 54 90 15 be 79 61 7a c6 
5d 42 5b bb 51 bc 10 1e 68 78 ad 7a 05 90 96 eb 
3a 22 b7 d0 99 85 5a 89 4b 15 41 ec 57 83 c9 4d 
0e 63 f2 84 09 e0 85 df 8f f3 3f 8c c7 c5 34 fb 
57 b3 b5 f8 2c 1f 60 f5 a7 d2 2b 40 08 f3 f3 f4 
cf a8 d6 50 b8 3a 2d 60 1d 7e 0d dc 59 0b 95 8f 
13 77 46 1e 82 9a 2f 52 8b bf 3a 65 25 09 b3 ef 
f4 77 96 3f f5 24 b4 32 8a f8 2d 00 1b 66 7b 94 
23 97 23 f4 ca 40 59 33 78 dd d5 2d bb 68 c8 9e 
dd 45 7c 80 18 e1 0a 5d 57 1a 0a 80 67 95 89 18 
63 c4 de b5 dd b2 c8 6f 20 43 28 b7 a8 f0 e8 f4 
87 73 91 16 1f 2a 87 f9 20 6e 1d 76 09 db 92 9b 
da 86 4a 8b ab 0f a3 41 7b 39 04 ed a8 7c 35 fd 
45 18 fc 2f 88 ae fd 1c c3 19 6d 00 8e 87 c4 83 
7e 44 8b 0e 59 7a bc 91 b6 6c 0d 82 5a 9f 29 ec 
bf dc 02 31 74 2e b9 c9 f2 b3 e1 85 e0 3b 5c c3 
cd 47 09 d8 3a e4 3e f9 92 80 ab 0b b5 59 a2 0e 
6c 96 8f f1 84 fe 47 be 8d dc fb 6c 89 56 50 3c 
52 50 b2 7f 65 5c 0b c1 2d 96 d9 42 3f a1 96 80 
2c 4d 6d 83 0c ef 63 be de be d5 a0 d5 ec 2a b5 
b4 4a be 27 d1 7b 6e db 00 a2 a8 9b 12 b6 d2 4e 
07 75 a4 ef b8 54 fd 69 3d b1 95 cc b0 8e 17 7a 
8c 1c 11 3a 6c b8 f5 ef ff f7 54 f7 50 db 35 58 
b9 a0 f5 a7 95 e3 2d d7 cd d9 21 6e bd 6a 45 96 
0d 87 ab d9 3a 31 47 49 79 31 d3 d4 1b d3 40 92 
4c b2 54 70 5a 27 ec 21 45 c9 4a 23 31 42 16 7c 
91 e1 a3 ce a3 34 a0 22 bf 71 09 b0 9d 6b fe 4a 
25 a9 84 6c 05 16 82 e0 62 b3 e4 f0 25 8f c9 13 
d7 fc 0c 4f 58 a3 0c 6e 8a 40 15 7b b8 88 86 37 
fa 38 85 d6 e4 6e 5c 35 7f 0d c8 b4 ae 25 e9 b9 
d1 c7 98 5c e4 31 40 3f e2 e2 40 fc e3 ff 4d 72 
c0 73 29 2e 72 53 19 28 b1 25 65 da 85 4d bc 0e 
ad 26 be 5d d9 09 58 99 5a 6c cd 3e 28 7b b9 4c 
d1 db 62 a3 09 90 58 16 71 55 e6 32 d4 46 09 63 
1c cf 34 0a 6e b1 2c df 5c 03 d6 0a 6a eb 1a 35 
53 41 fd 16 2a 22 dd e2 f3 f5 a4 1b bb 7a 98 ab 
98 30 61 05 73 1d ce 83 24 09 84 81 ab 40 86 b9 
c0 af 09 29 96 7b 9c 31 ed af 0c 58 c7 39 e0 e8 
15 c6 e9 f5 75 9b b4 9f 34 f2 76 33 ce fd 02 f1 
f2 61 11 b4 18 93 49 67 30 0c fb b9 13 a7 af 7f 
8e 72 fa a9 3c 79 13 12 0e 1b a2 87 a6 b5 bf 0c 
a6 fb 1e 3c 9f e0 62 56 24 6a 23 72 e6 64 6a a9 
0d d9 0c 77 85 40 4d da 6e fe 75 ef 87 e2 d8 b1 
e5 90 ef 0b 63 1e 79 41 1b db 0a f3 0b a5 e3 b0 
98 e4 73 1f 32 b9 77 62 8f a0 da 0b 71 e0 fe 7a 
ae 65 38 93 50 c1 e4 13 c0 85 5f a1 77 68 da 62 
28 e9 5b 50 0f d2 89 86 1b 32 7a 77 b0 20 cd 19 
84 2b 2a 83 d7 94 48 8a 6d 0b 19 98 3d ce 57 39 
88 28 17 07 f2 af f4 65 2c d3 ad d8 2f 42 4d 92 
e5 bd c3 24 f1 80 22 a3 2d a3 54 dc 74 6b d6 c9 
3d 7e 06 f4 31 ce 5c 55 d4 e2 64 5d ba 35 dd 4e 
30 72 27 86 77 42 29 5a d8 44 a9 e5 58 2e df af 
d7 5d 5e 4a 51 ea c7 6f f0 e9 d0 ca 89 35 5f cf 
3f ca ef a5 94 4d 4d c5 44 76 17 d7 e6 43 83 55 
2e a0 9d dd d3 49 1c 86 75 bf db 48 0f dc 05 24 
82 97 4b b3 9b a2 63 18 01 12 3c 7e bf 5c 99 92 
b3 ce f9 b1 2f 8a 5e 7c a5 2b 3b ca 66 96 35 c4 
e4 21 3f 29 83 1c f5 61 22 ae 10 94 dd 8a 41 c2 
66 9d 4c 83 b3 ca 99 d0 75 93 0c cf e0 69 fc c2 
e3 27 27 9a 35 2f ea 30 13 26 70 d9 64 d0 34 16 
f8 1e 74 3f da 30 8d 43 71 e2 67 ec d7 ec bb 4f 
b4 93 20 3e ee c5 7c 83 a2 3e 1e 99 9f eb 79 84 
11 9e 5c 24 55 f3 ea 47 c2 7f f4 33 45 21 0f 29 
5e 7d 6b 3e 52 4d 60 62 7d 20 b7 f3 9e d1 83 87 
42 ef 8c 49 c3 0d e2 e0 a9 fc cb 29 30 2d f8 64 
16 7d 7d 19 a3 06 af a5 7c 65 42 0c c0 74 ef 39 
4d 2f ce f1 fe ca cf f6 91 27 b7 fd 6e b5 7e cd 
e6 02 af 72 57 e2 f8 48 5e bc 97 07 ee 82 db 3e 
0c 73 1b e2 3d 37 de 46 a3 d2 ae cf fa 30 5f c9 
e4 34 56 72 11 2c e3 cd 20 34 bb 61 9e 8b cb a1 
d7 62 f3 66 ab de 87 84 75 4c ba 75 c2 cb a1 48 
89 5a 1b 1f ae 1b e5 01 fe 2f 12 3f d1 c9 17 8a 
c0 fd bb 49 23 9c 4f 53 41 ec f5 13 f5 a1 63 35 
21 19 d3 99 df e8 2d 0f 7f 24 ed d5 0a 78 c2 af 
a7 8f 7c 5a 0c 36 35 ff 80 2e e6 7c 26 bf f2 e1 
4d 7d 6e cd 92 5d 8d 39 7e f7 53 43 96 72 42 fd 
31 5c 45 79 36 78 5c 6c fd a7 0e 7d e8 7e 54 62 
3f 4d e8 96 54 71 25 ca 6a b2 a5 cc cf eb 58 5e 
a0 1e 97 51 7f e9 2b c3 f1 a3 57 e5 ce 47 ad ce 
c7 05 8d 78 df b6 cb 80 86 c5 da cf 5c 74 53 c7 
cb 41 98 23 3e 77 10 88 91 38 12 10 ae 80 18 40 
65 4f ff 56 e4 e4 0f 18 dd 8b 28 25 bb 1f 20 1b 
39 61 87 ad 39 07 f7 76 0a dd c9 e6 a8 fa 81 94 
02 eb 31 b4 79 99 16 a1 9a e7 fe 76 26 21 b3 c6 
01 b7 fd 6d 34 cc 69 4c 05 ed 42 67 d8 ab 32 73 
a4 6c 99 f1 80 18 33 f7 7b 17 00 ff c6 3c e5 3e 
73 6a c9 04 5c 4b 90 40 7d 4c f0 05 9f d4 fa 3e 
e6 80 9f 6b
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <sup><strike>9997</strike></sup> 9334 bytes

```python
import base64
import zlib
s=zlib.decompress(base64.b85decode('c$_WQ`CHltqNs5;i2^Zz#v-OEE^!bLafvlx4d7C@xFl_^F*7}GO%bBDb24qGndzV+RZxSPrUttJ5(-}yktk(RV#L@)Qmcv080^Woq!vNZEVWiUnRD;+-1i^&{QMFRs9UZTH-cF#%^m4V>{{<WxGcy%Y7O7M=Vs)*UPO>JHVJ>$6=SC1e{ECUU*LTF^=G#Gf9yVit@i%)ANH4^i>|v5tY^KfyI{;u@FIP^y7=q&HoiQ(J&^d>$g|b9<k`nq4r&y?$yo_DLLX_*z>O!$>`KYuui`(C$nO4)D)y!B+=svWT)FhyisNpM<0r%Ef*bEf7Hzl8?ACtWyl;{JtYI|Q^Y?$oLc4XGUk|yTpT8nT0hyo%SOqp^({^w@JbvB1@B8P1cdC9SuvD9;UGt}TjC^QV@9c&HS{skIzRMcnk}=K4{gLK>8Vgd4WZu#%`&47eRpUbw<vIjp6bjL0D-*V?OknvM2XQh8RV68TVMKx4F1L7R{PVuv%f7#cB9Sbny<BpxAb7poz7Fqx{_U?M8?;nEt{sh_X>q8Gxk|$>{vb2n=7A`zC#YF*w3S=eb61DQLz~7Mc%YNg505)8R1IstulHY7_<Sc}jA7A>%NMKPhg~uRL}vH~XuE&R;80k#y1=(V$xumNpusUI!y{35<`mj{T$Q^t*lpN~FlG!8`S&DfvhIj|5rE1;Tl@LYjfTJhV_{I>`JbfX{Gp!L%oh!ZB*5Dj&KV<WAbsE1<g{Pr8w0Bo5M61?^OO0mDwi_PG*H<X)M-g5%MaPKt<fjHV9evN+~@U*F*x)8TrrL6l7nSid+lD%-H&fTY!F3F*oI-u@bMFfHEaVqCVR$EPN-z=MFMGn>t6_OBMywr!}$-4>OC;&@r9ZLQ%f|44RVS$)=*Y6+zWjZG^VKSKTgA3%W~Ra-v?WDV8@gov>z6RTTk`vzdSG?IHeWs+ZO9T4}xN7!4bo}>?Vo>28*o4NM75^h8>Utdz75@c1ETrlVNPb>+mk<)a_tAlD5%TCh);O4he=#e^KunO<L#%;fF$(&l5S>5zlpM7h^i1GEyiqO*dRuBeuJumTlb1Glkb(DB2#`=tOzH%Y(Bi%RA?jrb08o+%4@!PG6mrb)NPeiZ->I<cgLs>m4lA-x=xbLY6QNjPPYh&LEN#;DS?z9-NL5=<VDkfjH;c%UC|LFn<%33d#VL6zzKAk0RCO;Dq!&efk4_^Lzz+Ziqg9-X!P{B5&cLHym`o`qc?GuL5IL+J624;z4IPv65QZw3`A^$ILoa_}P47PlHIiF<2&0$)*h}k+us=tFXhWB|y$mm^{sXU<8R;hi2-~s4uR^RU|uQbLvK8T7c3Ay9-8{P!OiuZ*<CG;UhF0{Y(gmCs&ImWTQdK%TskZy#7HlHb=!DbG;oEeZ%BaChr081xIUH1$1FECjv76<9;nIcrFC3Ae74g>+uU&f;^)A*-RpX1M-75xB^vZui_k%HZ!IgiO>unzM;kIvG-B13kc-dKKoe3(P#}k@>PE8aS=$6yyq~9H`)QbJaiEj(eaog$>JR9MS`Us_8f2Cf=S>YMraG~EK}}Wg$}2NXl&AK(}Mif)&vEoR@Dm*bHV^JIIm0ZxI##Bl&PKs30Rj}$5qYA>wHG59JhESG{3Yu!RYDYPQ*52R4UzFMtW7VUk+PA=LcMVJ=5@n%AOEUglK<)i$+Eks6r4wEH@78T!aBsbs1$a{1e;v-0Q;7tcW9>nj4n{))ZMx4u~<<l0`>);k~ki`vjIPb~qy6gSm{3raRR~!X65e+{D6}e><FYjlc#zwxiNQm{?i&>`~jt*waFrq@YAS#bYK*Z*JQ8_)YYQ!~o85i?d!VxRJ%>7}>J1J>~84CI1dA6&={S1bf!SwNb1orFA`GcyqxL3BS=fjd37C{lDS(xs56)SSz}hxW~n#kJXH$Gs@&oy}it_5ILHa3oa72BA)IU3?Y!gGWrt)u^Eb1iMo<mY!j~q%*wsIFSGVGsaY#F1xiQ@6m<X{zDpQ8TZ{TmM#loDC;1MSW1CFm=U@&>Wn<4O$Z|p$S$ofe9>Nih9wvkap7lriq$9JSQ#zO=&g&97d(uBB9)B97uXDzNPF*!RJGX)=a|=-)@fc0(;1;JLeL{f;pMV5<LBzsj-(1$6rfoMh5m7D0$;Qek#NKJ*t}%dD*}dCg_C#CDe-}nqDCUm>95mgt1jk|Nm_2oX-+&{E%Sl|kXr65ss;h(1aqYzYvGMN-qnYCovgw}}N!Ir5Zka-NEDWLHpXZARTCZFb?0t|SZK{;~$=vT(Q!CWZhgHHQhv4pOBI7w6HHXZqv^1z9d7a+X&fRuZKc=djOT!5ep_*7V@~Ny2*zO#f-qqfVk}9jcDk}cz=upfM8R)6f7Gc%>P10?#qX`jYKqtI8)l;=gv*fAtF#ypr0#$5KE#LZ@x>*K_T@GGspUFHnz62-B93JOS0JUm9Ap`2xg9YpnvJJ5=P;EHU@<j{^{l~k!E`b+xD=?^Xu&7r42VJM9$cbFb%Tsf2?{_d06=M^sb2WempBQjGH4ww!&3{0owt96A2$Sjzik%61wNG7nELCg`Xss6}73VYhsE*qkTfQPbRcHQ0_6d*&S04^d0EL5c=reV+1^5t(`cpsJs;C4=CsO}@!0U@kS^@K22BTF*?uv<>Xs1W~*l8hD#dlS~f{n1jgBQab?&U$t#-m)>H^m*GW9WRhDPf;1Noghb!Eo=w0zcd^gJ_L%ZnLgn2v?2v$!v=(Xmn2V-Xg+77|^A7h`|D$tz4@&lX}&JY+FJ1DmZcw$TY@Wiabzd+VkgJ#HREX3T^sEaJ)&2Nl?!{+FMcJC`|VcWOCgxLMCm~Yu#wjo}IldpM@jWxq1?(Y#Lw`IbeNqOdg2Sz7&BU!k#dAN6q6)2sO&ww>Y<yYY<1Wm)bM>^olX>%V#l%#pVLnLs1;!3aqT$xn@gt!0<ZNbi}3CXANU_XbXPBa%Ja^Ylnk2i9%xK#dOuC#Z?cH%bTe3&<bT3c|$wVmeSjqy0>hZ|1u5xU|2{JXY`}o14hAPi?6&1FO1_@<06FhvTV9ApL5o)=u^lI_z56Zh@`534s0C5<*{XzcZR8+!pNL9((*NQibk}{O(T|}zO}5%9NzLyypFc;{ze$!2}B{=_`VO<?Nu$(mjj!U@Tpuvvmgy%e22Wv>JZ#bb^E&CVQ$w@YSY3q`l!;DfKcX{wy+a6eX>J6hP?M_>`w6Y-Q}IkM#BzEz<EVFsvBHU*OyG#V`tAfvF?Bhg_9H>x40Ta&<qH+cc_w@7osO|VkX(bNp1E;9u2CPC`)VBex1)M4#8^}{X98xEws-sXK#pKE79O&FS@TZ?G`u~0|2aDG3h@CcnY$kw&bjlwfNBxJZ%TBc*3<!JcrHhPu=-j7EVq_0;vwm`wI%lvye@V<a2c?oI~LT7`7>CY;iy@26fVh#XUKvdI%mNzoouyH+S=C@*&8Mapc33<ed$5Kgy`i23&@A_QMPhw}eqNMq_90WR*H>;b>s83!wL3o(@N@8l-@M0(k(0X{%lk_2NG65XEK%6Ykwp)f)g$`MKeU4uv}Ex7J}Z{e|m8#e`!-?2GI)GywbgiFU>Ey%QF{Fo-jlLaSePC79EvH!+Iw)xmHtfi6mDa<@z7GzB-#wZ_&9dvP^;oq~vN@4%@HG9b3=mWQh}%0@?EPLHK&-b>c>&jS{oT>F4)6SCgNx1T@f@KWUc8bL9=z165Jo(wN78Bb{+R>E0Cgl}(P6wGUbcH}G_<5LSQ!Lu<d((oQ&hSifco)-(TZ?pZU<mkaTX(}{Q=qxva9Lh?KO|K~^-mpyYGr8-u_z~7|7ALdnXb-*f(`zx}6Tp0(#L2l{TyI9MtDFWYi0%yLj&D}Pj_clXohV=}`o@yB@9Y;Jge-$!Ywt_XJkF%!HpGQ&x3bDjqd!H)hr_UKuy~ZqXFF}ojXWm^Il-)OSR)IoV7dIji>4hG2_GMG&%Sj8w!0Falm@Y}`i;cpCy4B({(=V_1I*q03!=^n5sV{KJJ0HI?<K9;>psS1!QHc_iFl72$3ioI-`TbBay*}rLZ*xf^HZl$>mw0MZLNh7H?s{H2Ejx&|F;T8Fey?kOP8U`0>2k84RrR`Wi73u7Z!&?f*;Jq!I#@KcCL9P-VEh1r(#nX|3Q~@HQ8k@!xAQ9$x+OPd9t_WqMl|3arZX<U|U@p_LWA*Tn?&82i7^z#pNYP7@B8B9<=Yu@gU4G%Ug9j_OacBdiuKL?H>=uD<3b!qrU{eFZ6rOLqDtv-uhS8^J<~%%gE#0!C15j+TqYv#8rTsY(Lj#f}S`jY?)3aG|*8KIjV|E7KMgZH_2sBttV{rutAl~OKbml!V#L=c9^v)gkX^O!~QDf9>~`jcgTZSJ}uIaB_JDI6orxio!l{L+rg)zh#$261%AnR@skp_4HP1Xv&R>_8}A?wSkC7s1);7Y7aPQ+kEgoPp?}F>OkeS}t3+{R*>J0@{MK<U{Qfbl4>KrZJ`l(@r)(fG{&i=v2P_@@h{PBD-h&N&1L1G9jSME;>&xE&tEp;LCF5GQfIbjfeH|2KFzsC<t!Us+Lu->$Gkk)kVk%f3eJ-&dIDo+W<IT6~#IM(>c4CRugqLv_xjh|2oC>y&D~XUC+#xkW@l}(0d+%|LIz63UZ<N7mRr(&+qItgO&thEFM}*!Iw*Phyx>98E1>0_?ai=_g-dhkMD@q=J$qHy^_A~$|W&9h9+lgw$6nk2nE^*~(?nQz=q~?`X!I?&BaC|<4IiCDZ_DX}bx33d7$WEkpGZAD6`{-PC`h0yF`R0B|uVeQ)i^_+4qfINI)7gp_H;7jt>+N&Hjq&}6gfsXx{TJZKeYO=|*Grn#sZ=DxoGF?fa}?PBrL3azPi+Qt7bnfJ%;JhpuPooX-}*|44Vk0vJ@0@)hHs}?FObk#lZxrpDq3`s50j`hUI$)|(l26FY**yfL07%qCh5S($7ZfF=I=q_vd3#`1ru#kTa7cwfr!LGPDT0|3dvl9MVsm1<EAO<QZ46=J9(%hmwwsyT3k^df(jiN#njE+i_(r(7v~L51-2~anfSa_Lt2st=F(EJE;{T9)-z#IdCWp2AxE+^aPz!Z{F+#heJ?~BvM{i1SLqR1likhKJznmIx8f8&zS;9$L3a!`i{CF@^&DCD&X`a6Opgog;c$8X_u^Ed0g}ZpJ=v+r_s=Jwy#wl2kib6Bahocflns$t)X681g>^ZpqcLpBm?&{;PtabLq(-DqsNt*PWpl(Q#trLWG6Ksj*zzrgC1&FT#uTe^N1GoG3gIt7(x)-pu>*tRb+b?X#~l`2fPnbc6<YH|S7cgze(-E1ZX+u>huThT;Iy#91Ft4cYdVm6NE>K(X9y~)3@^SFw$spjjASN1NIi!;-S<weKQh%^GrXW1s#<s6<45VMk{~PX#Fn9p?^ve2CWwTAU=eSoS%D=BGXKHd_fl?mTD25}WHbvw(J~C|xv9hRDOG;#=&d@5ye{-Y{ygq@R&@YPBvJZT@Dy<CZ-oWdzJgnSHJm+<@L}u>?yi{7%-N5HqGKK+xgeY3fWPf!imkg20s93V{b(l{QI1(W?S2MYkczrEO<gqe${8r>2Ck$A?u&~len=DJtWjN((DSf|;RYnXP)#)xPo+RF<#O*K`=S%MluSKBa7>3NT^ZkGsWZ<*7K_8xC_`FCP{b~_EbDn$))|H_2O@zxy;L7I?0HM`#9$R|GOyS4LJb*j3vSvy*hp1me}GCQOjs@!Ol^N|{eG`|zM8f$(1K`DpST3{7TW?k%}bRTVx6FjAehn=dN%l_e;K)h;AeM-axBaz*9MTCj|fQ?rY(3PhaYrxF!@W;s`z<<`?@Yq989u<E`@zJTW=Mc5;wBUnjCjwj`-|AUYzKuPQFU`Ol>l)!4h`m83BU*0hB(`<6{MjLj@h3_V^%5wZFQ)blPp(?;jkgGPYGA_9zi3**ESL=o+lRCriC2N|`{sv8H^Fym%T~)ogE(EKq49^eR`@1Is$oO$c-%;zXQbOxz%(D``($25jk(pSQQwHC;9sl5{!A=GXuk@2t<XcV8>!^9%AzF(-iAP_tI11|vd&UU^^0W&5%2Em)eruyu+WT5-&Lcp3K5jCyawYMJPsrz|B|uDUpl6jRNDyTkB84n~;pgfk-;06p15Z-;Dhn|%D{CwS8n*b8S1y|=pwRxd{foAz{;ahov^43pP4t>j<l{=4}CmVc@xc^wiSNP4k}HP1)dV}Gv%-8G-eYVECZc-O=c*rTWb_}HHfvpG4dfN5vi^jmPEq95|ZqGL@VaIV;(Ui8WOj5lDZ$7Caq^AXSXe+bH2`+skzbNDW!<>%o-c~9DyIupTv<C!D@Vp6pe=SPf6-7BpK+ID>H&8UyWcY$NkJ^h>NJmJ)n4*o~7tuC&y9|go!JxMF#!%4Xz@iQT7vB7?SpTeXNnx+g!0{=)RDRxEE?2|BXx~dR}Qf(fvphgSYVZcF<Jg77C;>>^f&G8jd0c3_|CXO)%Ye9;==pk$i|9O)O`30!8Cc+x1hULTh>kqa@-Sr57y$03o1N7Nq!2*CP+I{fK(gN>u<sI3e_NwWA99%bGva>9?Cz>F?UnTaNsE1CYDj*&v4H?e=-mAf54KEaEW@;+$`)iw3P(mSAx@EqjZmzk3`MO{;q}+z1jz7wab>^$duBNsDX6cXU=mf>%p&<m8G_oZKV)qzotE8eq$|C7a8S(g%*<)2h4@hDtVp5xwvzU>nKqP}$$p%sHx{W7e@!w^8y(*hx7`Iy8W0y(Mr{L_C)Auk<(yqgMYWZ0-U3sU*D^P}~^HePwpu~pXJvlG1_B~<mRD7=`oc^hWgiNrB^w%P2tFR{2_ETV|Qa$zVt)kO-vaE5w!sd}3vm+$HqUj{?!b>a#p_%ljTMT-kH?H$Xf*!AnTCI7YQ9R)t02ME4K(Uv`4PI1~X_v&0ifhjLiwM#A=+37-yPEC(0P+fHE_%5!rrOKo;@yIFI%)Fkx=LC+5Yk}2&rxi8q^#;mjR@3Afoz==xat$_IfG}e($I`gbV0Qd?Vzn*3BH1xd^t2ENaUHi5-0~7egO7@fqkWg+B}<>cQZXXC?&$SKvezI+Voi-=`y$3mcY1L$(K>Cn&nNa@k!kVMDn`v@kG$W;+crCsRd$FD<afI5^O(eb#JL)v8LV(#}2Wn#nNu*clO3I%XN2eYv5zOJ^x(EDqnQ?4gd%bw_Fe-_LjU+;qZA%PKKnd2vu5mZ$WlSgm$D1w2C9`g3#2*B$hHk9WtA-CcoZ`hH8d2EW~Is);v*ZTKLRVnux!v8YE^@r2~$~{#HyeEU>n*Sa0LTJoQ9mIX|_{D~ImDg=M@)-Z;T-g-ruKe1Ab5{cmG|gw;*)PqgIk6}Ns<tthOSM7;ggKVI)#sg_*s9u`zR=55drMP^||W3N8<4JLr=w}loWDvMSrB@;dE2DByLzOIZwo(KYb?1Um<2`zicENci{(4i+l*_pw>Y%r6lW@54tP?BR;26RD)r;fycGcz;tMb22f63xKqlNQ{0;6TUJ1IKN>IXNufo&{CEQXT=!m7B9%kg11(Iej^ve=P;!8wSD#hW6@+%ofu85Yip(MJ|tcvc}hXuLpq0<dPC~w3$4E$PC9zOH&v*BVc9HrlbU!l`6xyJurM~39!djG62Z!E6Ts>n7-GH8xT{5DeL*9gg!JO9+a?~+7}9gl55RDdNU64c-oJD5(G-t0rs(fx5bLDeA?5K-M!aYtEWziKOM>h-Bhy7XHOam5<s)~D;Ez~wHnCttOji(I-R7rnH5B=OoZjz`xfh6hQKWY3s$7K!<{*cNbHt8n{MZeWaGJcp)Q?z4}0#p%-mxD$AM_%m(CzFhEXKQ__@40mubAQ<?qs3A-^ODwDY@))NRvnbkiPM;WjVdqAzq>CI7aq8J?c4gXoOkhF?ErW<HY;^D%@&_ym%dGG2=wfG={Lnd?CZ;)Ugfz}o)^Xa4+B<o=qsxqll~*nZXHdG$cy|6Bug2h@P>j>1#UmAqKP+lKH92Ad^BU6Tzw^wo{>_Mg`DO2yn`Lh1c9K6i0Ekg`3%T^Ji)V+Q2o#qlhWN<SLeWII%4X^{u|;ZnAhSexORg&nI>-K10&4meuRgKh+kETZatA`Bg$(}R<ru+)Sjrb93eAIuge%@Yt1KFR|p%*s?|{oxhmXVbQzBIHfB!WHoCp~{X8?&9oz)AS)cH9XGyx8#r|PqeIKNd@q@7nh~;o}8mc<lodz`5#5p1sWRHS1sUL;1l(^i!#XhI92jBQ>~-o5H3(b^s2mDTtxrL=Tjvg<K!PXQ~CR^7};B8i<dN2R|F$kX(eJ<Tv8mkt8Hy+mH}r*Z3(9u)o!nyS7#H9Lq@tj-qN?tj2d{Cc+~9^!fvy)CqnzdCm)^M?3P>}tH`gFTr9mjic{T6e7|>WJ$&)2)b%T0K8gL3+<?iu^s*hBd25(I)@7T|JM^+fAwc}@zVK+Jc(BK7z8CU^;OQuwK!g>Zyu4C05oOjJLYfC*E=}x5lgeFOM{<-9LA*Yx4!%a(l1^cB1G*6)QfzPz{4OEtDk9055}J@?;=fw}Qb<*!5rmxg@$2q3T*<V*eTS9C<<rU^s<v|f`*~cb=1A`XfvL@zH23GQ^?>`Q!C(29)fmskQ!(CbetmagW;#6+F2BkKIEHU#I=zG(y)uVMOQe~M+<e4juhtA4)tKXW03u$|2JF`G;4^m!M*QQy{9hcRvZ*cw#jq?3`CXaFPWdrvI81VqN_QRfmnmyS6$!2VY0s)bJ=tn9Vq=rCy;~9UhH~i-Q6D2B=~ujAYIf6bdKlzJC$IC7?V~CuUOgQ%xaPO@lk)iQGAodMgpoHvJ@3XJydd}P-Kv>lji!Z;KigOIpATZd`@VYffcg!B@DXqArE@u~giL1`|Jpn0nU5|LG3=C|l5Rmpg)gDzPaTTebbPyrgvJ(?xRzD8vaN<WX9NCpf*FSTdyIH@=KSvujDiwW7kTziL3NGDx}XgK{>%Xwb{MqXd%^jv@Ynm22en^b$vb>(rbsfT3@<*B_8<7wy7q(y_OI*ahk9+Dc`(U%ikHl!Ht>Iep)=>;k1NLd>aM#hoM)bcKCH`u=CT*FQop``__spz!2=NO@274y6=vQv319<%f()_sZ@yals_HA`7xzXJg0ss1vClDB8M2WF85x8gfhbXu$G}2his;*1Cic_NkfZzqXejD6(^$<>`GvcMv=C<fWbHNcebUpZt4#I~`ttRng>ZOr8N8sd6#d+_9R>D&0lX!@-MSiXxQ|4<(<tabuTbf5*;Q;xtgOf0Nc{bY4mDRw>iX}w52g=&?hi4t=YRihxOF7?G|~cTQm>egoLmP2-JEAgH0b~Lzql9ClK'))
o=['A','C','U','G']
print(str.join('',[[f'{a}{c}{u}{g}'for a in o for c in o for u in o for g in o][c]for c in s])[0:-1])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Rbfb0oJcl6V5nlfxE6IfYJkhuEGKjSigILhHRf9IRJA9ioiggnrr2W92d1QdrGBCrBPWGnOM@dzeDy@@tv77v/3LLb4//mWeUrvb/o///62IfPM/Uvp/Hv95tq34crvbaQr9f5v@0@x1/ufj2Yb@scDjbmlwYvRIZmmH9DH9UFTyxlwQdMBUTk4evdpnnGNfo@iojxD8O55XzSFvYu1kfD0X2/rq8Fov7pvHY9KBGt93@Aih1baisPDyYuXNXlPfxQmQzw7CdudvriuerDdQX6@Vy@lolRKbgyo2rFGlql/aW6Ysqd1rbL2re3yOT@ltCiObxZyZiNsJA3bpNYfapcBtNoiijnR6XBk7xHvrP1i/Cg9mYlv3mU/eeex12XlLJZmxI2mhv3E6qYmxv4QmNf3MgO7HJKjQuCbte@3dB9/xkVcU7YgUzBwAGUPeZ5lvQBx4nbdhHn4Dwzqd5jsVHnlvP53dplTzXhUcxBQcXCyiXn/APXbviCwnj730Wer7PhgrVlsbb8LPW72pvava9N5xdT1PbjpU6k92YuZDlB32Fqh15oh1lvMEuRk/vmrA6cstS1g1cV2moVSsptY1/NJyu3QVmelt3XN7d8gqVaPWxu3VbWM@qVwKbl0zUJp8A9n25@E1n2La0uuttt2eup3Kr/YIVfBVudhmedXBK9aQWJvXNzW8vQYmfosLfJS8yuOmP@31yavwKFPvqDFJb/wKPyBT5iZ2pfGBUXCV/Qh5tta0bXZRfqkUP3xqVfczt9PswL0VKqWPLBL3@JFaW99ggA@Y6mwqLzz3l62Uby7@tEyorcheM6y8URragq/sMrtl6UYC3mWrQxmXoFTBpf5AotvsN4rGQM9Y13gn96Tg07kLKKlGrLIPHHXibY@lxBgT09HK8Q1QqrEHHIZIhw9q8pbaDcxUQCm3XNx7z@Yw7ky7aF@fz5sX/ukfF2NEpDR42nA71elpIT8oJxC3hJ3P6j92g4yQF9xT73elG@HXtX@uR3y1IdYcdQ@MWiMklhoZa05Hjiictgm3XYHCYtYo6OloOr4yj@5xPpy@n3fgCzbazJwja@ydOCjLqvNpt1fbNQjTyL5bL3bBYaxv5bWsuoNWdfdbnRp5f8dve6wb50zRXalqaOTFeT3uS6K9S@uHOaG2v68ZDrTN@Mv0tzGD9ZC4PZviHd3rMZvHucA7rIUK6j3azhYmU7@EFHw6PgYR36mqnAeT87Zn0xVbl7PrnFIqVdIZgVAt6qyZThHdprin@@hYePvJHDmvsqGdTbKLGpnoOApNiB9iFYN@zAuxuoeGfnU16Ad3s9mL69U2CyzG3cvdhGcL2z80GImyXCVlLu1o0HjRL1PZd5ezYLHYezVFmFVIft0viMZM6dDUlg//jp@0qhvuo4yuVLXVOle2Srco5EHYXHFzkk@Amu2E7aOuFEX94Ccu0dCARTns1CxFfF@M2Eis/jhTOpJSn3SxNlm0pUXe7SwPz5Yx0EFJiU/H76KNLyJR8kcUVmuCMOJ9w3qW0o@R5u2Gnzd4uehlqm2o3or0fKzxS9vZSl9tPtnSVHK5p@JWa/AmGr1yAcz97IBQ3JjceKNmuYfcC5fWpMtOXZ7lqpqGh3cFFyPRpAHeHJOxYB@qwxPn3Zs99CVtRBRERwIX5HiXIsirZN1HXGtg422XqWebmkPq8ABprG4aOm3gnddQzw@Zfwyr4gGQXH/OZNdiSoZSPm4M0VZoNc6yHNstaFH5hiyzEHqnNQ123@/kR4gGvDQnJ18IIPsUuyAzWRHTtbFJjz0H4xx6zeyn99P4J8jf784Fv9hMi2oDGfpOfQeu5UK8YvkLYopbfSJJl@bhJVUqw6i2kNNWcxV8wU6yHzBPcdwhJp6wHpetfQas9vx@sUQ62Kq9KUbTxw7fbsL6YkAr1nQ7oTvstTqYCxs3kinYB@tCmHbv7acgsnhPBU7D1ExR8FSiNpk3mksSf1g7grkG7WsJw4fpq539KCpqGgxMhr/QN/JAWpi/5N1115eydT@tVj9A63bsesl3vzZDjfZBZFWK58ufLS9l368xxi94IM/T6J6w@8G6Yu5l5IBMlr0jvN8vgV/c6/j9M7B9rSZVBv8yE3TC/HptTkLPg26NLteo6QDr58xE4/toYPzFVPJSWsM17QTnFs6VEb@GXmmnC6/Xxdd77X7XSjjRRHCcsrX4/fUfxz@ViqdWfMKx4QCWNq3@HnDHu/sDznTBRP1pTF32QPBLqsgzlUbr8XacnvaVEfryl2z3Qmllwd@WPfVQqpdpJYp5jkSn6x3KjS70hq0xuyvVnoOHzw1cg7FjE8zM94hnHp5ueHT3E5CYrJeVYk7X3BqBn6FsOCTgIYFnGl/MFiMEWE3GGkyfPnQDZh2rCZEoOVFspXTI23TboZRhkQYNCAW7dyeeep0LzjdBcmmHlZk8QR7f6plHvmfOPXIVjrcb32vCc5sLQ3Qu7gMNws/scsRirVGvlUJ1HX1C7d7tpCnpQegp2Rf7fDydNZLrnotz9/n9zgDp3jmEp8ZM4HeKeNMOg5XKHUZmv/n4rA9ySf5AOlehJcDtDp4riksvb9/mQwl/dkVROyS5jhbEGT/VtZqzyg6yRZ@DuQp07NsRwbfsb/bGkGJecRpJ4mzDLxFYfPi1Cjq7OdPeCu46@NiqMgu02a8kmhHs5eQh9eCIpN0ccQaPUeV9uzcrYEcWKsqBfTGIfFTZ8Ti9bUbitehijSHRmszXzcnmQgxuBvZyif3tmk8mHXpBCuKGpYJSL6NfCAiGWX/xdF/Xshp@b2PbyZQALXNk/hmKg/XL47nZpad6amI7@3IbLoOx2H4@gVqrbMbPB9EdYOA6KPyw2kWfszF@FRTONbQ07X7x1nbvpQKShKqzXJgrS1w2j90zUls32/q5KSgdi77b2zqqdx6QYd3SSUpybZpL518WaG7YcK2zMoYN1RHSz3KK0VJ090OinsdXztH655RXNHCHy5PZr23AR6VxgRlRvyDjHbFbefzCIdFZ7HomIMT0s1lYZ92dHJXq4aq4VyzvYzkI5DSkXa7YtqG5dRz/6APcMz48@CjabC3SvrXJvj6aoPzlYD1Bdc/u/JNZnOvb0J1UxJWgtVQ9FU4TuIbNoj5Q1kdTa8IZn621m3PuS5lyl98@qzyD@CtF59uUDXavBO1D@4ryNCTTniXzs4utC7w23ABh5TyYdZMujKXz2vPJ7Kn3fk@huwtsThk9jjSmuq1E1cptq1yVFCWB1ilRwdeVdR9AkzrMTP/b4rTBbHPUTG0xPFUnJ30fXUPMJ6ovuXKeZ1zl0LfEqqnarRplqi3rAz63F3sdJO8m4x0@aNZ5bT5YOdH2xjdG295g4fe7NXQ0R48s1eyOvFzd/olJ6cQwnemRdCw63YPHGp1WO21yHQoptcI6rHp14DZTCAhCZkvfDL/lHFI/32L@7VSJWaG837eRRZaFDQLYd1jSR2M7p/qzDIQuQQBsWPWW5fnFfVdtDNvlzORQMU1dqHHbJfhk9@t9KzEigOQd2dLK57t@6toaM@l6i/70yBjP7r6x/ErhtDIshIIStqM0H4obZP4eV7bGY@Dko/7Qc4@EyLzaTfVUoxKxblnHJ4vH6fyzDTXInN1QgSQyjFtwBrwd2i8UnrYrPf1bakTvJTzTRqrJlZss4MS8Nlqz6qE/NrJf84Od@HHLYznrugfDZ80MoqczG74mh6o6tJAWBUysu@gtMroR4MI2OTbJ/HkxnlI1yt82u6VOmNWPpZ@i4gbOcHvSf7NY19l6FW0j52epepkVcZy9xfqa5lik1pueblarRdnnPxtw34aPtWrs4LicLrzn105m0@RINHcrRGRIk0l7LeCptGKInbG9qMFOm1AINbWyGoVHbDbudjRBrnb34fMGO7ALGlPZ3rSz/Cu88Mn3UNqfS69iG0Cjj40lePx@mq4/2jDCu7oclaO4EUTKaW0vOJwQchGoS0/4dREfjt@98CeKLfBxMWxUnodjjTjnC52Mk18@Y9tVVhwTZou@7Jbet9pk@8JCEeVaw2Qsphasy1hlRm24u@bc2QtVWYeVdxurZyoEXaDdziSGnjO8NzTL@ooRmpwbfaFF9znemJb4HR@pjrJeAkpGnSEoXta8te9YMdyA/q7rdthQl/CkatC3XNLJKz8RiteX5x/5pzcut/d@fO81suMfZnzwgXK@amYDcSCjeH276q0JVRQsKtW3REwf/Gi395vVtxLU@O8iOFqRFntb@mvE7HvIEnty4toNENg/H0dtEo6qgHgbL2uvlskHyRkQYe9@3MjZ@3dItNHoGwfa7qJLUQOer1ewFG/xsxT4TNsbY8fxdFyrroPeE2iOTtGF3X8Nn7Ru3Ls9hEqI3h5RCUmaLYDWr510W8qTSVOU@pRMkMwtXaPAUrSO/ijCMbDl/6GEoZrD0xv53pUD8nJ08RCBzOXZnB6UmYeL/bQUMSF41T4jUu2N7Hc/nC96G6PJYGGvvbqvjJ2PtzL8ANT6DkJOEkCqsLLFKcSisRU89A5Vrtqntfyx4rIXssBrsCTAV32@OBOP4y6ZRp/W6X7QqM1nw96Oym6AqNd@rYf5uF5UbrP9Av8j1CFB0fuMdTftcXXjEsFxfrKGZz@Tlb7I0BlPtUwguW9Ke3To3udKwj/yRuate/qE@lWrrlBpAhzaCepqss8rvbua7iElqDjf9V@c9uHWafxBerIUbD8CLk/dg3jE0uHjsS3v2R@5/OayeYmAbUWhLULPYTfU9DnwW/IOwfyMwHLVw3ryzaTT8DjhpW58f/kxEJVK/e7ChVcBsS5aHVxXbBrejm1xgWp5bcUce99B/7kOOTxFYRLf46fFsh4Kbry49b8jZh7a6@@jVS9XCDNpsuVUpjbl0jGjNiPfDxMjgtg7DDnjsubTObY4sqxXLoZ8w6vNaqiCjolgPRVIpvYSag/hRircqDNeOpIZOLb4weRRkXLUA9ikdSVrMOA4DOFwG1adlj1p1M4SH9d3lKR2fxVpCjFWm1tlbqLkx1fgfbCYY941/qdtuHrlFe7Yv1ZrnuvVjyIV3dbmQM3wy@oO1eqJ9HDntYcnjKZfBJCeyMJ7vxiiJ6BM89g/@fTRbZy9cMqzCT0BE/GtHwc/8LOrER5Rj9wn2P1LrKugIz@of10WdPLrGxog9Wt/GPOh2pLP8Ycjr33N1x@t4eBOCG/jw4DvGmXjz6295ntkrJrDT7a1l7CvH@vtxJFmEoy7t6NI4sGDqc9qYpDUvl3XSbVXqU4Osr2f0x9kfL9W0gPNv@LxqO@cvv3F8K60TsXCry8fuHl1JlVy4t2yRfw3RX6RP6jehs18wjZZ2BPTb380N8NKdHjdb3zSMtJOMzC8jQTCHyjCuqM9grwdpYlXE87rrCEQPzgjWqKTY35uVQz0nlVC9YRbT@cOKOMFrzY/rXMeEdNtekEpYTCnlod2l54QUNW7PJ/pW22F@tmBAn9WuQZC3T9CdwjPf0oHbWC/09VZn47KA0sf9AgSJgJZqgTcKCrSmdvdsMFLqOunRQEcylG94tmT/m@YT0sfXSvJCo380JMnxfUivXpOr1asSQL8OwfA8EtuxOo1nuNrmnHqzm9u7JIW2NOOf/xwbrrfw21C5/X7MaUnz3flGWGhb3aHJy@2nOiagg9Y6/ZQl9EPt8RSbsNLv1aSi8fJVBKowSfp7IEsdrcIWlYed2U37sppgBTF3eXQ2kitZKqtz9BxPG650gOHXnDjljHIY2XWzb5W@UUG5iyuptWl9uJnjVtuYUMNAT1o9YzxMtVTSeldIdDRo23tz9tLdyYwMqQR7x/cYvX16AmmtyAYrGfoTPIBsrGmnra89Kr6@K7t0LRCpV2q3dlOw/K30CqjK3Hr67mNcbunOtjQ9jpeV3l6ONZk8Xx0ov5F5bHOdyea@ROa/LjPKye8FT8fkxW6dmY7b7ts7Mu3m7CrGrtfDPPJQWX5N8UdGvHuXEzc61qcXOoUq3wzpv/2S7zamHXEZCzL9Zdr71vObuEA/iV0sWZKtLalCUXlUkKhXX@NTfehVdyFOeUmNlj27gzGheCgn9V@kX2l@cljF8wgiF87H3K1v2oLuAK/FnF9NaIqc0Q26HV1GmVreXjCmdZM1Q/hON0dKASXj70XdzRG3KI0f0fB5K8gDH/@THPOFq83qeBSvylOjQoBrj7j@XvdViYmErTydf5GvBt6sb9jbjkPUhaYR/rsU9pj41NMew4IobLB39Zqq8TVXT@sfs2Vun11R8HA9q70eVaNjjYpwx45sKeN02t4KhBiqnLBx1n273uotfBO@/trBLA7MjUKijL67D4hekRGCQZbTNQdPbU65HO4uQZc8AyMxmew2RdytliONsY8YiIYaHvGpdcabpCmN4QMqltOAyVgvdZxq1c7z8NoCZvR4gb1ySB0x4v9eHAkCr@FIMJaoeN6tOLuPofNPkaZ5j1RH70vVfUHx64ACXLSJnR7ZbColILxHLQaVbLQlub8VVQh3jAgEOsEIXRbL5dPkSOJNOqUwIAea1nIYg9Ks7Y9BtCJ6qAYQQ1/sDg@JBT95OfaZqPrzV2tU8WEC2zfs3dW36mdRk2xbi25E3Dv03M/nSzSe/H5s0N@c4u6wWrGv9Vw2Gtff@TNdcIG2eze0M6hQfLe9VPlS@657l0Rs7dG3x/69ly9zqUTD4qS/GviXG@3bov2gwmoqKTbX@6ytdiXpT/99WzRDr9/GQeft99xXm30xg17vxW4g9WY0xZyV3fm8SuKTn4bt8/OrJP7enBZCAnR@RySscJuT9KWhDZ@bzcPOhF/AHHulOgDba3ZdVPEjHoaFuaM3wEUU40b1o/g31J2U3OKA3h2e@vebHq9cLoNfHiT6xLPiLXe5r2z9uAsnOgeM5tcJvC1jcQ//JFxtTfxcWNg8pqOKkC1rRWsv1TxfIj31zfV1mbXV90FmiUNr/jVSxD62GeovX7n1XfpQH9/4Lnr/fZgjaiJi@McyTC6Uxv3gnPTah0/nDaHq3ubIGn6FoL@h5jDc6PVBHqcVX@h3kZRPSZMTmxjfe/gb7DZitEZPksADOEWdal0ZMidMRmVSi37OHvuBgRRNcf5iSH6XMGM@purepqlAsrt@QCp5W2xb9ONy8DptGXhJOxYsg4asP9sLaDLevBihSQ4XIqwZUznJZl86wUaFPjzZDI6eM6Gs5TXupa2oS8OU73VqEtvfIwP8hZOivgh9OwE/HD4qbeG3CpCwZjXZj3@sb11Xs@82DBXOVl8QfBWTcVXucNtFnjqvTeEeC/ckN69XfMNTe@lcuTgQRZS0Dtxp/vdodnYtNINwuuL708X7cXzlv1u2iSPxuhx@KMuKx6njdjSvZ3rz@5D/VldYI/RqsSOgrr9LE9gsX3A4byRn4TOE0jP31Z@qYNisgnKPmAyp8rtWI0Cdao2QrEvgpqDAIOrykn4fkms4EcTmwptGdrkRnshoT/tmNeavuMFiv@cVgZ0vYU33guBg5qLuiMKx2oHuN/nckyyb2kkVeFR@KIVrt7Zh1@s9jfv9RK9Ql6CFdsaOHFB06/TAzxKzvhrQ6BkuOa2uTz3t8UVaQ1F9HXWH5gwO21Ev9No/nDbneOsk4Q7tz78Uoy1PGga16@Bazm3C6m@jf0GbbzB1sXaowoIyQx3rV1nJzYEwu2Uvxo5G47BHVm37ly6OoMjnjo5UkefQ7ZZmShw3lO2UOWL7a6V6yxDrGjekqraDLP3eaeYT/QXJPDJddlvu@eq@TyO7MZRCTZ1MjkMqgtZvp6xPOtcDuAuWrsXkEefGEcYbquCIUPQE0Ni9xg0OCs@GJ7YO2PC7ielMJkjB1VWVttr9gLy3l7Q2Tv2A39lRXzbwp9mkPWpqaiTeElcJO1zLPmfdOFdesrCjQOpNtzGPZNtdGB2Susy/rhPEoEXiSuF3e8spR4Pb76e4qTrylsJrqTuEUmJzChWdKdzvk8X@ueza816VHui3OnnN4p3fD5d34cseRYwfvhWirl0eMaQvDf76OZCYUbhW8LM8kuo7dcj5Hh7MvvqvRvt2E77segPVyTWXfHwnXTe1tgqyMfUxDCn23rJSTRblk2yq24mqCTPGEmbZU5cKzlhqak0cMGHRDV0URSS7OBvTKAXJNB7rvmKt@uy9WrsZL3O3r9B08nnYeXW19My5ZY0qfOC@z1bYFsAFxxRzMVajgy3FiHeI3MDREb39Z5k9@mvRQDnYNzFDoDQVVPmijfGYu@llh3eVhDCdYHJnKif@r86/iXcqNNZ8efZptu2GvGE70DjxqN5TyHn1TEV3h70O3JjCpz2D2FX@PJ8yniNoffGNXF@unSoFP7xpFD8nuKVezzmgQ9JjRV@v4qdIT2PD0FhvByv6y3l3b6VgrgMUCVizUzx0buW04O9O40n1g1e9ov2t1m5VRuXFw8OpsfqBeKKkSdo8vJ4ZNvNS2YOllQ/SVuDhj7nn/yeheHZKr@aob@Ykrtge04GRcL8NfIp6U36VtvV4nnojfrCfUeJe1Lnq2zt@Be75/EYo5/OmC6V67nPHUh44zrFN4Z17dSuD6mYTtJXEkU/5HrQxPMYtN6f7jBzMY9dMAGDVjaXQSIv6pEsEtjgrA83XbV46s@4ZI5T1@Dn2PtqKB5qEXLXbwqha7Sqqj7x4W19icWVJPJ2M2qt2DtJ@osWvcw@5OE68Nb2a75ya1eJachos9a@2NnKlb0/9FMPp8fAGLog9F1R96wOr4O7SbTsgZS5dpXdP1B5tPrcqkja/5Txy7toW3NZDCXRGQI7MeZuv1Lr9WtEXMCDNWyJhDZ@v3qV@2eR2H/SPLMJi1@9Hxl/exeLiuJzYXQqnRua7lbiGk03ColGkO4DFc2TCCwYLplfI@6ILcjUU@zCq4/XXaHVIHcpGVhoyx@30vEvOez51HmGrT4jMNQge0Kpee8SPnriu34Rv3fk0IKIDI6B63uNV0RCSdhH0Ehm/UeAncu/LPwROuDkb5hLrsWZu8D6tN9aMN@HaLgj9U5cAt8q1a6Nf5jdBKzBGGxW1abcc5VWner7mZ4i3vCMdSAJZnH1M5nqdWfwtL5ssZXrEwsaynjR4zY6OV9mTxlwmcM7a3PNTjwPJsre4RCB/r46kWuP5tOSahDKANm/2kD1BEWobg3RMdKFl06xKMr2XHjwIdHsdL4Ttk/SzvO7NCkE6NwvL5cFsaSlItQWsdU1wVHUfaOnVP5xDORnmTQ6MDQnV9hCxFrjpd5njCXAQRgBO5c0XAIQZ9qPy8ndkZVufYQNQ1kSxE1Foosx9Iaz7XS@tH/TOmW3g8x7DNrwQ9Z2zVYGfrDJyBiTbf0CTJHl8l0SnrXKD4j1rARJv2Vw2mm02J3vudRDt8nsuFw5l@vlve6CALbdN1PYnNCPK7FN6Dv3Jn/ExhN/fmPZ5bEh/cuCwV5yuuZZjooJB0oc3t/@uGwzd5fV12kxZ6MQ9pfjQXyeurdY/OPfljZ5n8/fRUPOmSjwgQMp@@5cug3Uw9lgt3vHsVxgyPJaMrgLbPZzfQU1PpPbtXnddD7KuEVzn6izutxc2OWLxUlVbdNcvO9uPoH6r1XB9/LTjNppxIy7OchorZ7fksjS8jrPAt5/7vBQLXylNRvzr6/myiVT1Z5mOU20c1UPcnZ/vWCYfdVNMDcZ6G6mjtpiKWR47FH4840n0Ps4l5CTFxJ13jKgTdUPxQgQH4xk32CaIUN0ppyZ07TixVPYtGRONDKaU5HRMr4ZxvGY3goAo2dzFsPb7y6dL/MWSlBVB4KP6YF9n6L0KA4M/FVoE7eZpmjORfywN8V2o17n1XMdz9QycPzFPD8lEZTzreMsdA5FotkB34V0kGKMcW5Nc5qjnJ0pzizb3NwOj3ZF@hmPx@r6J@75vTfrpedu5Vw/EiuGrzUjDWAb07WvvZafNgVRf5CdqabTQcgl@Xq4c6c5s0pz377wqyfja99nB3PpWt/z2w96v/K913yE98efn6UuL4ztxsplgTUmwsAVm@ZPKZKI4CL5Hxj@j5j@9z@Df/7XP9zf2vyt8T//9R@3u399QOnj/p9B7F@hf/75X//@t/NPefqW1rfMvqX7/ceJ7/86/cu//iv@1/@U1v8ts/9buv9v@V//tv7r/@xJ/wv@d/N/N9D/gv/7v/8f)

Didn't go quite like I'd hoped. I was hoping for better compression by turning it into a byte array first. I'm also really bad at combination theory and thought I could use only 4 bits to store the compression dictionary. Base64 really exploded my compressed string, something like 7.5k to over 9.5k bytes.

Edit: Used B85 encoding, which cuts inflation from `6 to 4` to `5 to 4`. Removed some extra variables and generally golfed better.

I did some tests, and going straight into zlib compression gives 8859 bytes, without converting it to printable characters.

Preprocessing it into a quad char byte and converting to B85 is 9345 bytes; preprocessing, zlib, and then B85 gives my best compression at 9147 bytes, with an underlying zlib compressed size of 7317 bytes. It looks like preprocessing helps the zlib compressor maximize the compression size of the outcoming byte array.

An interesting distribution count of 4 letter sequences, from `AAAA` to `GGGG`:
[image]
You'll have to forgive my terrible matplotlib effort, but the pattern is quite interesting.

- All 4 character "words" were found at least once.
- `CCCG` was the only value with 1 occurrence.
- `UUUU` was the most common value with 87.
- `AACC`, `ACCU`, `CAUC`, `CCUA`, `UCUG` all shared the median
  occurrence of 28.

Comment: FYI, DNA/RNA has meaning in groups of [*3* bases = 1 codon](https://www.genome.gov/genetics-glossary/Codon) that codes for an amino acid.  (There are only ~20 amino acids, so there are redundant ways to code for some AAs, making it possible for some mutations to have no effect on the resulting protein.).  There might be even more non-uniformity in groups of 3 than 4, but of course 4 is a power of 2.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript, 11651 bytes

```javascript
console.log("0"+[..."ag77159t64gzum59mvzf4cilqkps21k2nb6ptu0dzvab52613aj2yajk7pg4a4rb4c6ga8cfpt22gi0v9au8xk4z67xbe36vz4cfj9mrx8pi8h7xk64vn060uqprqt9k5eosgmayasb2xdniph12ra241s2w9916kxk7pfmbou9ftlo9zey89i08hzjdzvz385it3tkzx629o1s0euwex06c5nwa8piru6wg1b6wi0438nfpscrf7ll2xp4qo406zggc2zllqeo3y0bzfsddfl0dal3r0ex07pnc0fa4zjpkipsl4n7yh84a3u20id9k8swl5q25h5mcxiv9n7u48lesnsc8op0lyfkgrpcqcxviirrjuvw34gr5o21ktfs6bf8ctg3lm1v1up3fo95as6m8d3g7dp6iin01mboe8xi1lwwmxum4m1yhdpb55jd9bwoftu5s95ub0vjze7qdqw2ctfq74262zmsjkxtxwlskk26sr7lb15f4sibdbk1vjgpnjunz9eo7x57w93k7o5vliq87vhj81fl6hiuoamv96ky3xx7an8tsi8qazsp56xd6w2i607657ikv7udieep9ituhbd1s72t92n9bujwd8h774ufpr9ftc2d33142eya5yfhmeb8rrshh998dw74lvlqsmsn8u0eyryq5bxos7qz8ddfeq1rw35ehvoxrh6b6wepm2sa1khkiictbio3qj7f2slsm2tddlmdvrs38v3zlvdo4m2n49n8p2pk18na5v6nn6uha7mo8cdgrxgwwj52wq19ju8cykixy41ydd3mugw3fpk0v2lwlti221hmy57uhceu2x1hd75ivokyhehfnegwslwah9c7loy2hv2l4btk9r5krvvo0kobnjktos70cz83opvaba88m746e09bfw16cxftrjemzln9z4d59y1wrqd9xnv05t6dsg9xjdhr4t0xnympo1a6m96ags952s08rciswvsnj7fumolrc1eo6tm838plbmg1a8820mp49w4rvzldnveqymzs4h2d9fok5ayur1oizls01f13uiru2v8qhof0git3irqm6lgvf8im4d2isifesp2grwfb0c86y6t6o9n68n6mlkybqoswmrwtivgei6tcjozdqs98f157bfh1c10nutrb6g2lp3he6aiha74dnkbq173cgsql0xmwki5gl0dpkcl27p8x4wiwus6ulsihsyz5u96dafeac6hrti2l5w02i26ek4kolv6dyodwmtvph4ecbhaof3vbzs8fdwg3n0nehzcl0yb9sdr7q71pu8g8ur8c5befxmta2mamoyco4dm4jhs1ukw432gl8147jvpm9ibk3ahu93df880qdd9o61fznxqbybyb9jwrxxgivord0bcwq0aukk0at5sdr2l1v9vk4557suerqt0xnzb3ndlk4hg3nnt28yoi5lqspjqc465l8qvafgmbgn0b4v52ujmis7n55l9qf9k3zqkm2dvpoc44sps0txdgxkrreaae2hnwr49ubwbcffefhynrxuauy1m5mqv5pfhps58vo0u75dct1ctgxd82syutibaox1dg8so7xj5vms6jh8gqkbb0s6jqatrufasjtdu1e2lv0qenvt70s3ud7adu0lf6pn2qrmwu1fwwp3rcqz6bmx4w6f90npamwjkttbfjnybg5kkn44tbsqzniocpcpxraoupacled6m7cw1xt16kd0azemms8weakubcyg7aibccgwigbmrwzw6mkypnfckwt2k780ji0e9ztjyowczciy531irtitn14fy0yi8ax94ly24jxni97kj9bww4gaxwf5bhxve4qfm36ws1gcvqo5wezrsl3lae0c56c1w3u1296p6m1380fqrxe6dyk0i55kqml4beg34dp9l77m3g8gq7ee0jxmk4oleg7rl6y2eutuabi22qzm8sllrzmhhj092atdurbx1qn3v8qr04abm0ito25x39d12ew5ezhdhf34kxvgv84kf1u6i67ebwqn7ii9x027isy4qke1uyb7sb4usqhi4x7gwurzt8i1hejsydlz0qpf005tay0fcfh5ldu6xw9tb8h4ne2uu2yxio83nt20kwtvho3a3ts7etziflksjwa5jodtum4pgaskzkhi38xgp5gil26ewan0e0n4otoq0kxyhyqmkkijnyinaxjj6sue1ao05d2ledd0p4zliqhzf1bxo3lp69r4y3d1y0jap63jcgmm42se1gz7k3au1hr0afdqtz7z53iof92ca6fbm2mot7e732ppzn3sppq6dlvbwbaw7925ohzvdagt9qlqj0pgv4x2erzmaadn96hwk33fqhp4ehndny0dyb0htl0zzblydyor1wv3tope5n4g1ff4w0ohwozzcnfffa6a8ex0943g36asw5etenmwbo82b4iuekli2w6ryx71yph74gvsjwtbk6ean4tznipkkx0pget40o5owmrozgvpys6gqu5q3mo2w5ux9xb1i4164teaz9sp3894901fpegqpbw73rvtc45dtekr5ewk2e8slkdhk0o1ziwaf9xde2kvd0zdeaipzfpxqp8e9ese75wm2sictt5f6ydz8j1top1r364liwhiaw739akd1j33bwgtvfjf02nrpcgflukoqp0nk53dm4q2yfchz8sxbtckkjafcmvkl1qx6b70hqgj8zttndddnih88d8hu6kpu7p3xsva6txa2koyypg61qvf2qet0aj1pjt34thokqol98faqp8c8ldxoqygvzk8t9gcj3jz8lhymf83ui8e2ahbuyzur7iqjjnjademza0oi106dtx7ysf28953pok4103cl3ftz9yhk1d743gv3wcdl4kdrpid5cshgamnzaxw1z81y200lt8croak8t9nxlqq0yhl3appwd5o30kpafjg8cf85rgfimdti8urzk7dpgjjkf8zs2nuq996thf320l1rjwer7ssrrwdhnwmhx8376arm5vgum4a910xzszwspafjrlgxnp71zjsz54r7r8x1hbslsjbbskrzg9v16sxwjdsq7vfs66nr704pqakunk7v5wfmx1316kz6k3zihapupvg0tmtxrl3lqy5uv3w0zk79k501j6841s38jkr0r58l3jhy34fl7jdmi1x7qejw9dup564fmb5hau1fbzp6hngw82h2e7knzflzxckreus941dty8blt3yh9myo5f8qzspks6ea8jbk1jcytllivihx99zcy2okge53yzuxxomuytyc3n2p76uk76gghchiuonlmq35bzem1wah2ef2hu2eu1vpwt2s47armod07mwhd98dd7gnxk0orgm8srwbpk3g4s5yei737f7adi4fdwr338tjg4kqyuauuc1shtn1kg2rd1eh7z95poqo00qa7ffou724esvk5dm6gdcpfbxn5ac1aej62u1hd4pigul2ke7lfm73otr2qnonzi7iv2b0t0yt6s0y2xaz34bgijwii704vnx70tnprovpjpnvguj3ipdihol5xgblqs65qutuerehpwlc01fwe10ybusyrunsxecrad3vlm2n8ecnitocmitb7npn205rl0nd54u66a5xuj64ma1reramte9x8ch7m5enk0kr7dmj5ao92h35k4c91w3txepetsdu4r1nb8p30b94p69fze23mv7xsk5gok7bcl6kouyhyvgln36coc1rijbvz0p6ya6oy1jqlxlv595qb7p5weucuie7oxe6xdibwqik5uupmb74h0ao5noxkadmjj2g2kpn8i0shws0muy004jhz64ioumtyvltlmoq7qqc1rz71uz5bv61o07nrdtxyapverm7z7i3qo9wi0ywaujm8k2iy14a5lem48k8m4g2ce59mdq67th8ssvyvjwcuigeqc1as4gzegp5y5xtx1eigeok04vbzs9g5dlsbv8f3r7s8u6nt1ezotj7585120m7drnbz5jhemyemyia13hq5vabo3djgmhpycyam2bxhb85201zprd60p9lkw9sjor8m55efsoi2d9edd1t5x0osp0et0udwxec5n0bb2fmlikz2xrenaysob58dtcjkd6ei2j8qjfe1rhij6uvyi4z268tny25xumiin64kqsmrl3smpruiysr5i97776kkpev50rh6gt1now0t7bfpmtek9a8xiwuw9tolgd5uvllv3ekkb3ebrj8z2q5yn2t8xqps4j7o7ic1hmy4rr7qxzsaucqszm1whv6ecwfsipbygg18iuo9n3vio44jcne0p3ma5dn3r7t6kh9w7qq0qe1nc63un4tnn50fc0b01qg9k8paea6ua1ife9bptjrwq3bjhp9kywqkx4rwq8pisbqc0gwjv2j8nfgexu41c8i8fmn5ldhm9wvoqyk2ybkibhu8virh2fbuz4cf3zowpjp87adt4ergq96emi8131bnccxfa4d79lwzvkmmo590dji3n50dqwyatz0so5phv53pr3yh2hjv1bdtym0f5675azzqmffs2k9jpubouikjlo2672oj5tccg1z1a99nd7lcfax7j1ddj4d54bj03brscs08kjh9vfd73phxd1zawtojedg7jgxn1lho4a0a9v4dk0hogl3coagl2gkvk6allnzqn14v5oo1m4mw5rhuvtcm11m5pa9j81wjwvwfzkn09ni5tw6x349phmz44211b1b3olzgh51swc2yezfwtzke3bb9f7un285445db96c6vpni7zlv3fwnb4haex2o2qn2zm5116mm142qcim8fy7xwzrcjnfwu5ut2gdk7wm477p2ed1ch80cuevr03xj8isgbbk4kzzjkhuxd3f0ndlaq7qcnwyhd0mmsmc4v1vqq5ywhlbqsuc4zgw6wjqoh4m2mhkicwpxegnipd7ojudcghpcal9bn84wu1rurd21mccnr35hgocp1c710pkk9cs8h9cetxja1yffqyfa6h4xxq7xkkc61cvcdt5j2gvcyo16747157luy8b4lr4rfnt6khmbu1qm0o83b055zkui9x9pyyknial002t49gk0lchqw55ehmrv4gmrgqqbjyt6zquqrj2m6nz0l5hlq9kut58cw5r2ugakthgo9z0qyb3en00cn4zm3huaxyzek2781mdyo3epzmahj4a1ddxaio4g05mtfga50qwet7svg3wjuadyxtdwrifcc3v1vq9acwacwrgdmx9bkyd9kp0memet0wcb0nweqonorpz0h66qmapd0155q4a9ir2dyjubjstl2koxhhljtavbgrlizxp9mp71mqcwihlu9femaolhlob3isl0o80k4lf098uwwtu6enywfrjpxtrdnq4koxsw2hwkpg44uncyo08prlko4jzpsw7v8x07vifaq8w2ld0e3r7fh4vwco7efrvf3cvrrvsjm7a4ikvi9ex79ugpzmw09573dou2eluhmnr2bnwl9pgytwng184n7q06nfy5qlr53o8e2yhqowbcbbmqj2q3k2vot5w2us7zpurv4q08t87y8ow21j72zx0nq2wig9l57bj0n4qi5n363x6pwu8jt0dfd1z47q10f7kfp3se7dv03aldytu2ul2adxbxqqoxha49r6j2rzl6d1g5aq3esra928yyuvoaw9vlaxcffd93zyuq10iv4p4mc76206bzz8zokkt7wxoaz7nx93eoonratzwc7x3y43sl5g1jaytckm2gk7g56407eeyxow6utw556jtgevghmzigvotv5xt400u9lp0f7rfbwxdzmnrrqy4dlg8qyayveo6094rhobjx4z2sgqtgdf5sto7vg8e78m2looefm7zw4b4vfjrlnkr3z9vllrtxsme6d16ac6fhpy53imt4juao885v07bkoftnpetqhtyv8aavtnq6z9iziggg1u08a2u6ufwgzl8wj3u9qtm0l65asnec4s68d623gis3tzkud5l10e9j1n9cys86g46l1qd2d0uhmotpslivf1r6rqu6xdnoq8q3xn9a5jhd9mrffiexkgqkcww73x6fdzif8bz16vv6k50s0hpoxbolaon09tn3m5s43bkg6ynrmvdqqjmoi84w0o6pda77yamkirecq5lbizi5b4vdykilmhd4oj19ef08ucle6bd3mh3l78l870b7gijrjw1shrjmufbs5fh8wltslympbz5ftppd3f66w4a4bpk0a063ymsemyxmkrli7x80p7u3f5aieffr00xob6nugit5fjncjndjuztba3h56asums4q54kylm76duw0voeaxl7lmcmkvfnjfa9y9fvin9noabbenuxebnoga1rdl5i4d76fatnatta0kixinjw98ta3jdt6igccbcl62npgu6agas64enniusijar9my6mym9sr9205xzrc15t3yx4rcaxxlpvzqfhpknhrl5podm812qy7jmz9pmvtj0eh4fv0tof331c0i7moq3e1405mmt77kswmiw375mm27y44zpm4j0yxc2mk58c8qc7l4wd17sfq3i6kyp099hakcwc3s3hh9n7pt22sdivx765z7a7yceklls3w7xysnn8gja3eao2ixcd7otmjnmkj8758hl8eobro69vsdr06v33o8g4ogjkq0w5mbeq51jfbzr9ley9slshdyzja9xftwxzylk01kdvawgrntccvbr3vderf92o4a3p3h1ary2qm9ybgydmlt6hgnh5qec3jo0ucw5qui39pt8szfcu0oul52ig7jaa349cdcwbzkd2rwoen95v1j1wfun97o7p0d9ct672bopbg5qzmqlmbn1vt8lknhdc1a0zacddpzbcq9yibckcuojw0wqutcrktsrw028078vg7okev0qb820acblykula9yvka1kximms581axsn6osdsvwkmqsu8h98v4s7avbuz8psp099uzubpfyxcpv0j2k163eml4ylxn0xn9j0uarlyil0dsb7vbnicke58bs7a771qwok9wzdwp6q3x8uld6a249t0tyk7utpm1wtctun939ve85o4p0gx11kw6d98if6dtn3240w1rwout71r5x13qoyrojmzddf8s9luma7bn1se4vn0a9yy6k4twtss2iw9m915p33dwsiq2gxho9d1l3v667urtjsydhkap5ocrrhf45p765gvbu06d1p6t0i6m1qtn1fwnk63qjf3ixu8t2089a3yc7t0ax8bla13jvywsfoob0aor0n1nvff9jd1sv8vhujwt7dw1cl9xefsnwaos76hn9zxps1ww8t3fp9bqtoqfq504sjh442n5zp7q3fqg9qcs1jgwwawxk4ijhpjk1p8fidnupykkg37myx4x0tqpjyi2dxswv37qrlsfujd7cmn03hjvmxw7m0pubwyfjuewllyu95z5566smtfbewnturtcvpbt6pt84psgjwgy1mr5nv5vhll7ifabnj3c2qjd3egym7rm7sulwitwdywtodg7oxdizt7sgtj6usn48mqcorzryif4icjz1ba6ssd68jjyfq7t4aj05u16o56xzx7d8uo0fatkx0zder4a6ir5mdqchr5ridm4kr7khff3umbmbm00soq3dsrh3y3psl99k1iysgrni6shr412eapflnaaoln2ujnfpiiij3cdy1ud7c3f134ytbha4whzfdn5x1etbo38p8tr0dwitoi1e0urjjnn0h2zd5wvofh3rc436837t2tq71vcavz3hf4q1cga77to7gh1xh7jv9pp5k1r7ym1dd8lu3pyegwdas4o033zdox52y2ykgwc0olukohvjd4e8vhhr9172dr7s1nv0jfm9j34wl0kffzdkmuhndvl10s7zg66x67heoiw2r75h313ylprl42o5c1cs5txdxeb1jmix6m58xhdq2e0h88tqov5gg9evzf1fueqqrv7f01ld2hy3faam0v9novd0tf577224osb64ufd0oy67asacztzklmgoeym8izltolk65etlefma5s9lonif0mg66gcbquqi2rqnj8d383ksulsimm8zl3e0ttlvpzxdde20vvf6402fkqkrkdl8dig3f24x5qliewi16flh7l7u0kq9e80omw1c63wytoqma9iazb07lacjlmw4uxvb2ovdabsoej53hiavtwsbyeksa5k1jyung0pq348s72e685nhzul11vk8riiz5cvu6ep2g4b1ph44ox8oe3le2rm24xu123kmu1ogcn1nis22tmx7ibe3b2gm5g9mvz3adb9mmz6doc9eaovpbrf80ruq83xwqmxdzol1yd007fgty3739vxkcud5qi1rgf2jpljpwrxl8v057fcjuk1eabvxnnmy4x6kpmq4zzf9t9xmevpdf9vi83keg5d0v1m1mqsj0cqnvcxacxrgrr89mw5t2o2n1fovuikptuou1acm8rc6hi4u1lgyzwczc8u13lg25y4bky0c4feezpy7r8wwkukrsbw60louy3fsklss79z61mwrkmfeyaw0x69gv9yk9fnuac2bo4lpe7hdd7w05vobhbcmv7m37775m6y6ja3sbfagb166sgmy8rfk4z39hbvqxi8jtje8o20rhu46u4bmympwxfv3jdjmse42yxk4mayom6z3nnb0zw8ftif8egdv13xp574kuav7o8amk1tsvqrstt2ndxwg63vsc1z7z1zrpoffrt2dtsc68efzkmzcbgspcl284nj2xmh9sbac8aiu6zroxeod2wpd0zwu3mt8ch55q7cjvf2q64gydgr3ox5a7tp1633pc43c5bg0xv6yhwzrfgu0iumib90subrlwcasb696d8h9fvib86m8fr3ivue2xux4uz87yjmh84jg7e2x3wlw8sjlr16jxc4rg5iqg3q932bew5sb67psw133lvn7tmp469yx47guu2xjg64itww5idjtijxdslktw32q21chev8jeb58q4q8clw4r779fntdhqw6bejioi2juvhbe5a5stzpjwggvxpanota0eb6o3zvzbtjpdsit62qs6xtvsm8hpavjihduq9qg396m932tsddvq0jfra2oif1a672j3tn3iekf9e41w8538rfwwdielbmnban772g3kp79bisj1ly7mhgj9r0wzr4yhpgojjtnbktyphxmh2clbb41h9v597h5d3t4a9hc4sb9fsjnefm2f3y9r57m4il7s3tw1dnbm1h7374a0w10w61esz4xagh258hzpuv8lf1ss0uwsjc1gyvttaymnbiclu934noga02bvh1rfgryloq2twu0mxz38p4v8zz3pgm3hc4uwypje4myqdwwi0c4wtm2b6jtspjvb6dkwza1sdg0zn5qd7jc59nt4o8hkgsbad3hyek7s3nkzx948l15czo5s8ao7zorbv74tgkw6yb0ugxfmvpoicvt3hmd7pi6ppeab3p6rmf4qjq4auapwf333ff58t1w5cqe4ctkhi286smvmz30m325hcrbf6qsafa8t9x8cjyz7cf95ekcg0xvube95ef6kst4g214yaa8ata3xzytfkb04ympre89eitlb4fe09y2pt4n0fmdfart0w1l9jreppceeq0iujt5ki6xqeeb73d7ckuu40kkgrseghy3kh0j0a9hsq5xn7lpg4etujj24jl8b9ta4l40gye08wvzdksdnq6dd3x3smmbhxsmjjfiulqrjqty9hxek5f1bdb1dv1xlrlts30ujhodfq8pax68io1m052j0l24r9euf3lmlcqb930b9i9yq42f1mgbj53is2y4a2h5jt3p319evlhzgttf184lgluctt12jdsvh6hwzevwghrgfitns6studbrw305iv9jitjiopfltjoj8mp20opateedn3fhby7f230ij9rj1kqtnuj57rfju62bvhfb8h8tghfy96330t56rigqwce3np7lkcctiqmhypxxv5rdwfwknkz9acsn8yy2kqcp9yvteqzscf801tzqko8svx3v36z0t4z5uwlclp5nynr3tzwv1yly86dhjn6obusdfe8vdxbp3qdhh81mhbdsnojqiizh3rz7ki3thywilzcg75xrbbeb9ggzcrr3u909y3og6ds9a5h83o01ivuoljsbi2lrpz0hilu3x943pjk0d5f0jdc70qsmmt6eqm720eittxi3fffd4naoq4f7v9gyu90vwm87aw9xl9a3tpnee1bifl63m8ppsb63z587n5wky81xvta6vcri1j1qbz81cgiy0ieklh43m7ui25qfd0tcri1wsg5si4bo8o23wkdjw9wflqdvupkebxascmk5aq3xznb0itryureyng3anwm8s0c2qq7dtubrkxicnh7hsiry2xiukrmhgce4bce4j0065fprpmn2apdv2mjlvdyksqgz4h27c2jcjgbotpvonp3nvxgc5nfr1nt5jgxtgjh801r9196jujlae79t887sgmdnc3i4wt9skrchzwqhxy64qcgjoknzszjsqcihzqre1hjmwkh4lqbhjff77jpdg92y2ur0rp9l3869r68av4y69gu7k86ayubivm9van3lg9v3sz8uo9v5vh6jipsjtoj4l4hildyukayjygmvercqwekxx6kgl5o2ojsbi068mocu574hczuk8omsnvw62e4kzqmg46kio9ptakc7lm0j6kcdqgwp4o8kl9kbzis7bdwhiyi6wilhgo3z7qzdfodv125achk0qmtn4k0l3fw4m9377av93sniy5jey8e06wrrncun53h5zvm74k6qcyfpb99dk9jkczbt7uud22kd4vnyoeja1u3mis8gf3vaph0g3qe3ts95nysf0wv5jmvqaqma44so6b7gj0m2jybsiourth1yx1vbbgdz1ax9ral19gg3enr140w6itolkyxv9gx08hnbvlatsk5e0kit2icu4nbliemvhidfj4ol1o77enax7maa72ur6rrdhkoznz3l3b3akwyjl7mcx39ow8ds88vh7ry1wkerurlfydegso0awj49l0detgare8fzuy663et5l3bie5466k7z3hfanw0seb65swwrltga7yyqi4ss76ln668j853gk0p5nikmwyxj6uuel3b85fnd1ak5kx0eacbnf11frgye11oc0lypfe7rkbhz254gwlssuuj1zjedh6ggyx3juafaoas6oy13ay097usxzk08rraw8dfbw0vlnfumayhvdzrlyr9bfaisptw250392jv7sh97j8otjk7sakxc8rbghe0g48q124nclebbyd2n36b0p25edqczjpae0zd799ilgtesoye097tff1bgaww9s90wv91lzyfh1pqlx52z8scd04f254fa3ao3cndkhs"].reduce((r,v)=>r*36n+BigInt(parseInt(v,36)),0n).toString(4))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HZpNs66qdoX/y22dk9ycAvm0kTTSSzvNVBogoHyJAor650/mm1prV71r1d4KzDnHeIbuoG7VluqP/m97Mfbvv5eyt5LsX6msf/wD/eNf/@evv/76h1qFwGzunK7fldmc78/RxaczHm3Ccdo1P/qFzHcrzSaOiQrTq0IUx0oVrZoufFVycUefptWje1aXfCL9uHi0Jfz@6OLCnOsjDy838URO7x1xdJ1HPfscmS1tzepVTU@P2f2x4amqieI2jXnGPD5wK5d1uWbXU5k/@8rZI7l9Adb0Ecl8Jz1@D5/mghuy17AP4gvbh4Jb1ouPFWs@PKJE7u6AE3Eipek56Fko4t@6LtOX0mkLeZH@XDPGJWRUIhXBlcSxL8gp@oUj@qMluot3k1SRa0LezFG2kdg5sY3l5fH3vIuLymTb3hZZDpReF9d6LOfy3N7XGq57ELpWVuBwu2tcO7n0laSMb3wdxJWZqcazNGQV5uDe7wjD7q18PE5j5OfKNON3M4dmLJhZj@L6xdrMLo3u8FlxmnNMS3enoBOfvtxCfPozUotx4q2KpDFztHltdMR3WI89XPs32yIeJsZMoijsTv6U4t6CxC7xzV9F5Xvm8SXPI9Que/PyVF87GH8MH5PnSHAmfLzFZby1x@z7tWmDm5j6PO2zvsIwUH9BL3dUKOUyGUIwneyr2Ou2bLWstW3bPEszBE13Oltuu7yQfet7Mv2UJs5PQnXsiesgzG53eerGobj2yFNTOG7R@6VrX8gZhJtaannqxqRs7tqIvMmXblNonnY67/KYjojlrtjN951fmxK5yMWs9VnHCGwaJ57DJZc3@uel@DWG5GsdxB0R3VMaqftpwlt@mbi2xV7TgzcjmL9LfDe7ud2uo6WhtnkRqbzTBv@I6h7nymK974Ji0XuIHTaGlk@ScsCMKSmzoNyiWbuB@fK4XoPNX9rnjxo2v3jU08zPfiPWuWnr/ASzVdrRs7/5KFjxPHO1QkNMDcm6@DbutsNxXLmkumBbeM@SyCPpvGK43YTyQedB6/0ls9/2fPPX6DaZ2ZXI1HtVXPyXGsIOkwsmarrluRWHVpg8X8/M03o76TM1k2/e2XZMax1Oo0Xyl3de5p3LnecUX32WNnId3d@r9bwvoXzmbLN0mAntNrxgtF@9ar5O6SCb5cpDXajZoz6xIMvazoSePKJnK0zpEZc0iUM@dPhxNX6l5rf2fuyauVHOqoVvFcqU2ECTn7iNNJZ0c/MWM3K/j43aRW@qOHLrr0lnxkp2tNvtWxJ69dxMFafAxyVXeVW5MG3dk7uassrlXQo1mYat4SsOSqY1SUxFuI88ex2J2q6ZGCclOo2ZC8fu259Tv/A1h1GfZ4VeqQbpZZxIXTEi1RnccUr4nu9IGRPtsiCTUNtPk92kSDdY394n@RbPYESOcC6UsyTPW7k163VHmt5sukL2TeyMpfl0cyTfGfNk7qMslLajof6Y9Ym1WqXstO2j0vnSQy/OWbe9e30udb04s3ze7HDb0ZiEhr0EM0vHIFiPkVN7r@61Kg82q2wgH4HdufGwyfWMWiP4eKpeL6da6ObCdko3Ou1@d4EauYxQ5kLJ8WOfzprHhd0YB6nL@XGdoaLczWg/VB4wI127sL96ZTHulHbdzm/3ZTmW46mqXIdakjU8i2Xgp4NrGKQ@m3OTw6p46eVdhfJ6WdbhVw0N@A2e43vsbomjT1FIFDyy89fDW8byLf5lBHtonb5j6l70eqmemaZ3ouHZ/SxiAOkddFXPcExvz23p6TLho@F1uc/Chv1qSyQpixbGFzzIhaeZHzxjIpE762OhDSPyjMUzgzDYlVBzzEmITFY4QmEtCk@OFDx7FTXxd7JXv5QG1Tm/LFtK9cvbFtA8KTjfqh987gSGsyKqdEa@l4k9ZDZ4soPZbzObIzQ@93pLGh2@uOfC6nHuwvv5QZPw7aVntPh6tWiaXu3cPH3EOq76denxZkN7TfrQeTgE@qNe5Ba3sWQu/oy5a7nR3U7XNb2PL5JAoyI433srRJHehO2fdym2MBQLxXTwsmNVLX5x80Q@68FWn2BKh9qRRTstvZwoPu/2njlGDx3gd/WEwGEssCqImQnKbtBBPzCs7XMYbIKkg8@VvsTgFwV1cBKWNWc6NYvXT8BYXnirSDlz9k98jPji5mlR3Ok85dKFFWQ6jm8n7ThObtINg6GGmCdWtu82au3zmc6AjvWmz2ShCEqZfebbiIS4czuo3Xazv8i8Gm09oe/T6QXJqXjcpJfDsp2u2Dk6UNlG@b5ld84priQAx0zJSrhqULFu9zx0kZOm/rIx@Wnw@j4Cv8cm6HrDOXYduVU77TAOR4wPLMp2igorILPlW@/jbXw9L3aSXKbBrmd@NPYUc9qt@uZ2EDnTGbT9sOt56CFIvftCmek2VmZHnCx0WjRbRAV/fig3P8ZO8TboM1b543PHcx7SzrZZwQYYMVhwZ46/5pMBw3ZxJZwmPzYPp0hmFQ0OhOix9tsFh6Yd@Gh16YrlPNAeGQFNPafXLdsn26P7EmNQbsl3TPh8uBZoO9cgv953YwAZNykBLS4ej0sc5Gm34v1RUyzve6wcn7ebTtuRCvgIndC@lXiWBJ6jYN2LTOYp57veX5R9XpdAwifT9mYnwe2kndSmr/e7qvBnCHtQBtxYoeIx4qY/4m1ukjMjR4kUI7Ik4vo3v1vERkApbzIWk2g09fCGLW1bVd4/UA38SfxOCKUul1rU7@b7k84TvVsi6jiGYYWgeCgXVuBryerqfDbdgw99EdhwDSE6@bVpv8555h2Ge0IJ1zBsFa3VOgwIe94eSQRXNbN7hXlTM0bP177RfleuaX32Q@AvtI/RKqoEhtHATUHrFuu3zjfm7RnBtFPcgKt8rwLR4wRR3aO42XD5wQQE9@NgMuDVx3XcK@q5PxXE73zZBSeAYMGA@ggHLoHsiQyxospkImF7CXVJBJM9fsRpw5jNBVhJgfnZBqPq9HfwbV@HnLbJirh/Ln3PEqu92kyx6a/UqZN3m/NbmJMnUGlsMBQyAN@G5e0p@dtvzzx/yzuVuFpGoJ7PU/L19nch@3QIfkXB13Vbfqy7p3wSpsFAMNDbZN20XaC9@D7AKxoVcJjFIJHHZoBWjVj3B6ajrqDJdegjkpU29loviHBgcp4CVlRCZA8rjecL1notuG1gLXGdqsF2E9/MjnIWhE4lnCuXmKhtd2Qm89Ush9PPztSClQ18Avky9PDrlaZoRXJZkNLrdO5l/7zw96RRR2/nDb3Toz5C9erD8B4Kd@@PQH0/armPcOzQEYH4w/itJPasGoCCsxNMxla7HSMtoAvDYgChq7312ttjl6oMuRMgtLTLDhazZN@12MHEEasJ7YbRi3PFnitwmhWutqrc7fzIZROZ2T2iWIXJgakyTxthkS4zuGN/7GF7MxeteNfyIEjPFJTcfXYi@RZPi2wtUegl8Vgu8IR7TTvhS1lw9UHfHzr4q3h5cTjTk242s1OLA4z4Wi5vRQHDfYwHv/ORXdeRtaAbUoXt5YkKFhSmdYrHLj1q22gIugMhgLuPU1@u3N879ZTLKc4T7vgJfH1M3xwXJPYKSvCq47Y1i094cpYZEuc7FHCYjJN/MVUs2UxllJmu02IhaZuTi77J1u73DgPWuFq4smqQxC1Y4csgtmELvy0RKgd4Oq/MpKZv6QhMuLz43rH9Sg@CSYaB44Wpu/5Y2Gx@4dsrTLaTQaooxIQ1b8e7vCpP@tm0ZBPC31ENR8AcccwtlCozY9a14gH@wVdxZw8q7UCgnpcZUHwGeKknl5OP3/RUu6u3Fc2kAZKPhls/BXkGZ3HdfODX/Xr6TVz2/QUSuTKkWQ4T0DJoQ8tHvfzbKgOaEoLHeNibIQh0a8d7GahDIDigc@KsIPyOC/iipNWAoKR0ExujJlZX8IHpZO8@dQk21GgQRfjll8poBXQHqVPXcrYPRnm7uV2Ga/7Q77piCZM@Ay/5QmlYdosOkhUzO5xt53GbBxQacBXvCycXOOy@M6AdpBE@V8j9h7KKXwpD4Jn10UMdJ9FhO@b4jjM@FH6Wh2/6XNA6wg0Hs7vVPhfFi/TS5R2oacvzuMF84vTq6PV2ydvXbXL6@j02IV8ZMKUSJKRTW9dz5jZ7CXKr9wWCoaJGzGl8d8y5sBmZ4AmsEeL/q/qHWmHHdoMxVRDHaQs31iCWGTnGBVPfd2bn2hTncFy6XD6GVCYuphJYB07GH1bzvBuRFqceEbAxAfIn1QERXdsC2TKGbb6dEeTYHoM/NXoJ1qwigKfgtBWqkJpvaiLayprIUtSapjXekauU9u8Esr5ZKTjTPFjdLuCOjCFzHGoOEo8w7uG@uKN596wP/hA6H1v@KJ0w1liTkr51Y7iNZXrt50b/oiVaz05c@yQZBYjRM1/4fexeQPInbuyabso@UwG1nL7MMOY5Yzqdi8/SveIZX13C7sbFrj6tJoqRqRDHZA1eNomWy94VkSdI31atIU1@X4jb9RjiQPqSAnVY9vFuBkH4yAu98X1Ce44t6bNdC/3WwUc4y0aBNbfol3E8dgV2M6KEyyzrdiwqzXqXFAJRvaqZcF6WvRK2rZB38CIwAtCblya3ebH9CQq/zp0v8ONGn@cUT4wLx8u9mM5A0u7lLZgLKiBhpwvMkqZKq9t/PZ71hc@MgNQ1YuyLF8SA@XjfuHuVEJo6ndeI0rKdA4Rhy/Wma4ZGPHUAf/nO66xhynz/UGJbOud4dSYXKOZ0rSp2WPEMWeGFQd0RWnb6ZbJd6nk/GychcQYmJvYAft4CVdBhj4JhXBHL3a2KoXPYLtq9khEuZd6ng416tyzkd6qzWgZ819XkZ9bxNXM8ULYZtGosGu3DnmUv9fjQxvmZ1WEQZuwEAPJ1Mm@4dGgdHLQ825ZCV7dea/Lfc8wZgCify/BbumZnsyppS0UT3xIcFYo0OTTLa4x@cbu/w9VwPL2a/aRwtTYmCALHSum1w9EjedQUCw3f0Ya45YPE7YE85ZiSQRbExm30HksR1tXbkeWuFcA@C0V9vP1sHzFfK5zRQDMTxBQgkXRtea@T3keaj/XtYwc1o7s4Ed/dy85UGSlAru92Fsj0WuczTCeJ0106G9PVxHdcUMsTyS7FK8uYcBDT96D9nCAgz4kJmPOdnp6Bw5KHH@OSoSPjYM6pODFyIrqDAPGbGxGVzNuvCXhEmUc/5wlnquhceZjql7jBK1Mnsa2qeZLve91FjflO6lmcMzP53guu6G960LwIPiGuv09@JcYuxlPUJ/ZnJraUvYKujUU85KWkJbbioF6IBxlURazAjAgy8/uUwa8ODctDX@29gmT4FXZ@g59ShK45HbD86vR4zAfnWM@XmrTK81XvbQuHBFa3osMD1tXWs6/GsdaLuFdphcxTKsUCc32Danr/EHqPlXywn1T70zKkeszVwh24LWTL3Ck0b5GS3UjoWBzQl@3nBjghlbr7fvJv9rBCcKQLSTVd/HJj/ZIcgVzz2TNKnKm224U2Lg2fyOobAa27DEsY2TngfV7eJvlKOQQkMxkE/VH60YB7Ha68npDOzV5OeZJnnyF6A7fm6py3T1zPuAyIZQ93BsK51B/m980B1hvajvLoklQBDe47yaxRouPK373m25xnyMXLX4jlh1FCAFpEX@1ysqRhRwyOx7zRpwy4WgKerUPyWpLl2pC8kSRkkgJpAXQKoQWAuIZ8Od2Y2@RIvaU3H0Azrh8HyCvngyoKdI0U4uTNDQDnyRFmVjwSHeIijilvnasIPUXz/Vo9xNCwg56bcH1dK7IxCNZXbvRkNL4pC26uge5i1ZNEykuOt9uDU/M7u9vv816U1na/Hqv3sgLLmsQ8uC53qu@qd4Wif/wOmUV2RYLp3K/L8iPUaT/Wi6tVNU7tvvur@aAqRBSe3zy3OgMtP@A1mEF0AVhY1POk4/5OaJu4bzVBHDBZ4ul8RcjffOS7B2Q36m7UiyMEL8gLoFFiMQXBzF2I2Eb2gwj4aRIvpd@RaUDvs0w5gizLcxGJDoNFcyfxPL4HmudNQf0X0si2zbv4vcVpxt@P4OwTSryLjSk1MsTztn2Xa1DEqjL5ZwHD6jnsOQYJ@LklaYuuhc93MxXxm4ACrbSsIZ5osKztyXCALFfnZN8ZEuZm3i@o@XF9PN@bIsLR3GqsdQf8uHUlt7HVzRNgBDnIhlV9pzPPr15fk1Pn27pv7LQLCQVd4Dnn5cl8dNk@t1yoXIlNHlhEKcCGxSxDf9FMdRS7z@zGAQ937TPA4oHMvHQAH10OvbLzy2fKesd3lwkqYYDI0acWY45PL@f8er3E5SphoAFJaamxQ@hDk0RC3qso0d7o1HJCatHpjVeCZrqjwvHxQARMYvW0nZdm2j1iBiYAG5c3bQIM6Prk0X5Fub5LHw4qd9woTBFzYnOib3p2BAMc0KVqen1Cpmlx690v0TKp4RpC4HOUOI/PjIPDuMsrGa4mOnfU3yiufgAI96XD3sl8W8kKPdD6YBwHhzDrHTcw6RNFA8NZXV3gyiDgn@WtBfrQGCfbnK6sBBxRs793ebDBl0faR29t8mPOM2YHIWY0f07rs5XZ4ERuzsVV@@/54RbVwcpS6@Yog@jNVtg6Atk8eEeeZ3xCMgZWi5xAliD@uWSfkJwVeRfRkXog8EOyCfc7mitFQ4araMf77dwcDG63vLcrjC7MwEuaH0g0@1ClCb7tMxh8w2PITtwx67OX050M0RY24MqdfYc4iQPAP5eGwzqGGk@kHrg@RHxI581@HW@MKxEgP/RB/TzCC3kJfP8m4qypuSsYseQdEWDu/AyRERD2eF247EjpvWb2gTnxBpSj7dg7HMtyH7pz6F56tDWM9cW5sv1m95aSAFzQeyDLdAZD7PpmASmzXWn4PswL1A3MXSDZfgBLa4fY1XYqAWBK/errHfVL@LBWvDXDZQivO0WnKiB2YV4Yf75HGHkVBKIWn99TvUoV95VBQF22yqo3mUJkj5tz5MoavhCEi5OYVjfyEvCZeY4YohzMrucg4xRPVh0u7QrQaZ8uAOrDew9bMC@@4HCIw4S@XQMljO1zZocesx1Sqjxkr8jAzorHFl01hH1H2/QZBkHJbaQulHBJRJ/6KfC9qPsj0EYnXlZofnDpdcPPJsI9HweLuIo3A1fKdJHjteswkK4LIuQz5WHTO71xHQsqv2eP2x0MtdA6W52xmAwkbGgpFFyeA6EjoejcZ2K@tt3cYLwAUSvnDxebLX5MVbCNYPImwD06FbbgpbH@GLAOHLJ/eGby2cw5WbRJ2c9ys3Wd7f057C57nvUWDuFkpu0lTqmMbnCf26DumBDTREvTnF7OoPJyoZpaPkCAlNdi3yz9lyAbR85sT8AmisGMlt07lGGJ66IB1P1Uzz1IQySJ7feaLGf5JWJR7@k@vscYO6H7dgBRk4tnrNEkafxK3EQfQEpvh8fcpU0kcaF4zlaikmHAOBkvTFEGrlafRiKpJaQ86PXceoIdKN2KDYxsHmhnNP3a2BSUJrzXvqLjJFQ2MVku2b59V8L4jrJ6/7HlBrw@ppVqfMBwlkcWS5KdaoYVXXgiUAtc1gUm37dp6vkRXkMAnNbM1t//YyAK8l/OHzdlmcG1YMaqk6hepyTPODPgX0n4NQgJt/aXCFDEB7TdsNPjuropHCkcoz5J3ogJt4QrYqv0/ex7funD45FP@n1u7vOT7X0YN98ezteuzKAbZ0gRLaDl3O/lUctT11rlDFm3Q/4EhSs3pO6jX@XCasmyLnzz9MJpfb/fKyh5YZLWib0U0g1aqLP2O15R5RjxirXpwVEqF7RLi6k1MX8c51FjdvZVAz18Xu/5jbPbL7WAu9F0WLEZIwZid9GbXvItMhECgIG/HJy9aadWjUGa1vzK6iL9yLzp@3w80H@wskwIcjrlF9WAMcd43A3UE4DF6PSCTmb1lsw/su8afUO6DkBpV3Nj8hxM0HipWxQJmIh7u8/aep9284yVk7st@BMf/upRAOH6ZHpbuLTui/lb9NqOJU2QccL05G1uWi1S@Yt/tTy2mGlAuvvGRXKXywYpTyzh99SfU4CFtRIYdiX6AT5KDhCQhekVPTd/N4j7br2Qv7LXM2qXrmksCkZt5gaMGSBQS56lq8Tfl52e66Fg0uINeZM0rAJ@RUYasoVUMQ/PQuvK/LmScyYTiDuDSwkIfpiQdO@i54PyGXxDrNc1PWHlFDR8MG9C9@ExLcU@yHROeNnsLYPVTJ70lEsatAoBpewGsjjXNvjip3Ddm7YMxr1/B7jGej@H2gtgqdW8kO/@dA@Hab7z6Wz86XfLcjvUHfxmrnOGdc48w0p7M@Y@Qeuqmop3WAEOBQIg4G10s6V4SEagIcYw3iadd612UKWVxEPM2reA0yvytoa5IjhS@m7HWkLou479PTYo2bQkrSne5pvNYmOGgAPNG0QaPbsWdhCtyZF3rkxk6pOAgDOw2XXGmyCCKsARNDi27aOPWrcJgBMi7C2Tw62ha7Sw4PW9gchfWJxfILgT@kN2NOl7w1Dk@qZyTn1cKD8f@Ay95feRY80EVnGN9wiW5vc0Y3iYtdHzpCE/tiPcmps4PoWbWdG3s9OIsLB577TILa7QioZsIGqw5j1@z0xlwmz5CmtSFfGVqm9B@wp89Wp0rY/L91H8cneyZSMOz48DNIUcvGbwsXBSdaljAOET55jseLDltHTpcfOTBGi480dQJhPblqodP5tySvbf4/XwfmJxM7Nx@bX3pS18djy2TtcJ01cpqSCmAG13FzWiMMHVytn6njSoC5rf6eh0Ry4bp2qHM09zqPY4FmtPmJHQWfT8Oa3VgoCLx@uiCFCoNruCa8UNBYDBrZ3s2UU6Vmr7FcJEQ5J67oomitbXIjlu8NFmIPkaQx7SctYbBOcQnL/SWcPZ33l7bGQOa6MxyMeTKuRBgq6wFeNOeaiHS19wRmwKKE20zvZyJOW0nHr@vTnw83vSyeG8avAe8IeXqmljoUOWgCR6p@1be3dY0rSma@kdTwGQfOMgCfYe6/Z729b3xlu/jK6DIObvOfgOgwdk00MJMh8TKofq1pqduE2/wk0EeRiCgCMw7BWYqEB9/NeDTstN9nVz7wwqhDrj1a/nWCzZD5HisnR/5u09nudm1Qw3InTTrJa2y/ed4rkckCO6Pb@2gIfh/p2xyHY/5Cb8Q51@7BppSQfbIZ2T/o0bv@mV3GwB4oa@mnEAN@bRBznNtkmcN23aXsIJXgtc9YnoSd/e4dO3rII9FZKvntf1A1An1wzdQcrKTZsV2yQpCIMilhSa9lP6/6dsHiAL2p8AKSPDHApmEeiE6nZuzywmBI3WHw9t7QzdVTmpE/e8Ag@je2Qp1JifBJDfj91arL1LnGR5HCCh5GNS7GzEV@Ln7orfS/WQ4U79SSA//yIQqrRRksXlJ3YCJvXf3xhtZc1TXcC5yIgGgvpw6TT3dUSrH9Ug8f8eTT0fGJbv9b2qffeVqB0W1BAQ9ylMB1eA9Lbsm9iahxT6eLBfULvFUg1/AkKcuaMeeZ/UYe4ph/R78NHO9aPbJJYpLGHVpR932Q@y38@6sN1VvHcW1qevYYOCAnTOPFwhKSvmLiWgfDb7Qjxo0dxiXbZvnNvzcnouayhx/9oX2rn47TurxVvII240nXoLzgkBsr/OALhXRfWYE5F8rlyqm76ABZeIkqv30v7O8612wIz5Ju2DEDD/MgcP/mihlwAjC2U17xXVG94137Yu57DxAfZZEytT@dUfcZnLcoHBb8t3RVly2@/BJ0vjd@aV8ugLJHMVF5EyCjwu5lzHAfoZ0xz155vQZmz@9Ry6b1vBucT5GVdg8iemli2iM/edRpSIGxQMS0Banknb/cuCfaVFfNS6L9cOmMm@OwNq8HN53aHn2cQ5xAWcUFyXmaZoILO@QKQKAy74JldHbnVsCDzbkt5mGKDm0LhZyPepgGspbYVrsQaUp/Dq5gsEtg2/D761Xs0HiX6uKmGYFWL3iiE7c//D8feB9n6Q3HZ9J9VbZBZF3ye/XHTXQNT53rxxgQKFFiHsrh6RlRJQNF4rxOTy7R9JRBMVxxuSyMtD5jKkaRJyiqgvHtHWqyb3Gru2gtQIdE7I2L4qkHb3XS/nxHYGF/GWUc6j@OUl6G/UgBFYGwOUFaLT@56eAkTytHMIiWD3a0QgJj7m8T6QKS8L15DM7QaryCAnWrXo3WHsKog6xmVB6T2cFTXq7ZsYXQdA6XUF/AVrNr6u70PCBWZVVPu9pCXqRbO42vNFJGtVsC2nB7rT7i7gyO02X01vnYFJfTv6mBgi8xRu0bZZBFl6AMtV8Vlk1etm0UrliSe6L8lq/ZppJ1yjY2IWUuwXDmUh2Yp59mntthXwoVl0Bw6zqjHmNkPFZ5y@1234OBOEw0@2xSDqYCtOEVXIspu4tX/871/Vmmuxf/xR/3n/@e//Uf@F8P1f/9Ov/7X3Pw4FZvj7cP@T8D///Cfa//yrl//u1e/rH/TPP//@@/8A)

Answer (score 3):

## bash + `jpegxl`, 25 + 1 + 7280 = 7306 bytes

In the spirit of @the default's [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/205879/print-the-sars-cov-2-covid-19-genome/205895#205895), here's a similar approach based on jpegxl instead of flif.

[jpegxl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_Photographic_Experts_Group#JPEG_XL) is a hybrid image format, with the lossless coding being the successor of flif. (it's the same guy working on it).

```
djxl f .pgm
sed 1,3d<.pgm
```

The `f` file is a 1759x17 image, since that gave better results than a 29903x1 image for this codec.

Contents of `f`: (encoder flags used to create it were `--allow_expert_options -d 0 -e 10`)

As allowed by the question, this uses the mapping `(A,C,G,U) -> (!,#,",$)`

```
00000000: ff0a 8080 bc0d 088a 0b01 0806 0100 c400  ................
00000010: 0000 5019 d3f0 014b 2837 b29f 27e6 8d79  ..P....K(7..'..y
00000020: 4110 0441 c931 619a d833 440c 23cc f82c  A..A.1a..3D.#..,
00000030: 70a8 5803 2162 c88e 9d12 4644 c430 c660  p.X.!b....FD.0.`
00000040: bd52 8701 0098 0000 03a0 3c6c 2ee3 b34a  .R........<l...J
00000050: ddca c0ea 175f 6697 a631 e677 00f0 1929  ....._f..1.w...)
00000060: 266f cfe3 4a38 835e 5ea8 32e7 9946 2227  &o..J8.^^.2..F"'
00000070: c18a b26a 9e0b d52c 2405 9f9e eacc 8d9b  ...j...,$.......
00000080: 477f 6294 66f9 f67c 0c84 b130 1dc7 a638  G.b.f..|...0...8
00000090: 8498 7865 1293 cc1e a84d 5bd7 afcb 89d6  ..xe.....M[.....
000000a0: 26e6 a091 220b 9c55 c266 5e66 5ac4 d64f  &..."..U.f^fZ..O
000000b0: 27dd 31f5 623d a8a7 d592 f7ca d9e1 80a3  '.1.b=..........
000000c0: bdfe cee2 e029 d9fe 7a18 e29c ca22 72de  .....)..z...."r.
000000d0: 25a3 e740 f478 097a f830 1352 8d8c a591  %..@.x.z.0.R....
000000e0: 3b81 dbd6 48ea a366 7283 bbe8 d6f1 c889  ;...H..fr.......
000000f0: 97ca 0689 9a93 5c14 0e0f 81f2 61ea 3d24  ......\.....a.=$
00000100: e990 4afe 78c5 bd48 7dfb 5d42 aca5 2498  ..J.x..H}.]B..$.
00000110: 2f17 c876 bccf 5971 f588 9d28 33d5 ee76  /..v..Yq...(3..v
00000120: eddd d09b 5641 5b8e 6d86 2107 2c9e 6ff4  ....VA[.m.!.,.o.
00000130: 3584 615e 94d6 3305 dbb2 f209 75ac 430d  5.a^..3.....u.C.
00000140: 119f dcd7 75c6 10e9 1e87 6557 8c12 7da6  ....u.....eW..}.
00000150: c578 7b6f e864 90ff 45be 24dc 88f0 31ea  .x{o.d..E.$...1.
00000160: c1b4 68ab 656f a077 9cfc fe43 9a0d 0bca  ..h.eo.w...C....
00000170: eca1 9284 b66e db52 aecb 7a30 b1ee fba1  .....n.R..z0....
00000180: d595 ccfd 21c4 9b92 733a 4602 8c79 8c9a  ....!...s:F..y..
00000190: ba9a 5f0e ebab 7126 c3f0 3a8d 7e1b f583  .._...q&..:.~...
000001a0: 846d 9d86 4535 47dd f383 2583 686b 9278  .m..E5G...%.hk.x
000001b0: 3919 078b 0875 ee52 f20a ee97 72b3 6fbe  9....u.R....r.o.
000001c0: 51de abdf 18d5 d603 41cd 708f a339 266b  Q.......A.p..9&k
000001d0: f8da fda8 3f4f 2731 917d 405e 08e5 c827  ....?O'1.}@^...'
000001e0: 4767 8c32 f209 bd76 ed63 5b78 e97e 7c18  Gg.2...v.c[x.~|.
000001f0: c975 c021 d033 9ece a33c 4521 3998 94db  .u.!.3...<E!9...
00000200: 27da 8bcc e326 5e3b 6fcf b2c8 7097 9bd5  '....&^;o...p...
00000210: 31cd 4522 f99c 3202 2f61 f27b d3f1 7b1e  1.E"..2./a.{..{.
00000220: b4dc eaf9 45bd 561c 8751 17a8 8a21 2ea0  ....E.V..Q...!..
00000230: 4e54 3593 b565 8985 640f e7e7 e7da d854  NT5..e..d......T
00000240: 5fcc cafd 014d 6a05 1c79 4ef7 3158 17e5  _....Mj..yN.1X..
00000250: 793b ff4b b0c8 dc9c de9c 2ea4 181f b6ca  y;.K............
00000260: 67ae b1ae cb04 82d7 947d 217c 266f 5277  g........}!|&oRw
00000270: 1ab2 f57f 78ce e367 6c5f 84a5 283b fcec  ....x..gl_..(;..
00000280: 4b45 dc62 5cbf c8af 2619 942e fbd4 f414  KE.b\...&.......
00000290: 31cd ad08 14cf f4ab 97d1 a5f8 ce44 dc90  1............D..
000002a0: d1e5 7f75 f7f5 efbd 628a f2d1 84b5 6465  ...u....b.....de
000002b0: 11a1 96c4 3aac 67cb cf36 cf7b 474d a2e4  ....:.g..6.{GM..
000002c0: 4bc2 5af2 b130 8315 a7a6 2ee8 36c9 b0ed  K.Z..0......6...
000002d0: acc5 6020 8bd6 1253 e7cf 5baa 4535 1a4e  ..` ...S..[.E5.N
000002e0: 66f4 e9c9 8885 9081 45ac 4008 2ca0 2b83  f.......E.@.,.+.
000002f0: 77f4 9f71 b205 f175 7163 a54a f488 e833  w..q...uqc.J...3
00000300: 988d da7f b812 dba8 5821 1c2d 3641 d28f  ........X!.-6A..
00000310: 4a31 d53f ce58 ddb1 d9e5 c86d c546 eebe  J1.?.X.....m.F..
00000320: d723 8f58 bef1 78da 4c06 424b 9e4f aa74  .#.X..x.L.BK.O.t
00000330: 6e83 445d 6666 5522 64e3 7d45 bb48 a47a  n.D]ffU"d.}E.H.z
00000340: ffd8 3fd9 ea85 2820 1384 b0e6 9820 ff03  ..?...( ..... ..
00000350: edda 6768 67d0 d317 812e 7ded 948d b76e  ..ghg.....}....n
00000360: 347b 58da dce1 b29f 3140 669e 08b2 8541  4{X.....1@f....A
00000370: af1d 64fd d1ba d8bd 5872 fae4 97d8 889d  ..d.....Xr......
00000380: f28e 0ed7 9cdc cd21 c3c1 872c 965f 5736  .......!...,._W6
00000390: 498a ceca eaec 748b ba99 4a8e bf70 4ee2  I.....t...J..pN.
000003a0: 6f45 3a6b 10bb 4f45 fbd9 4ce9 58ac e37e  oE:k..OE..L.X..~
000003b0: e2f6 724c eda9 6112 1e28 2a7b fd2d d91c  ..rL..a..(*{.-..
000003c0: 276a bc5a 5f4a 8a6e 50d3 4fad 7c36 57d3  'j.Z_J.nP.O.|6W.
000003d0: 87a2 483f 62c4 1386 69e8 71a9 c869 25b3  ..H?b...i.q..i%.
000003e0: 189b 98f6 820f f39d 5fbe b69b fa6c de17  ........_....l..
000003f0: db48 9d4c 42e3 7f05 7535 5409 4cf9 fea9  .H.LB...u5T.L...
00000400: 0c31 bad2 0af5 1709 0b02 4cdf 27b6 1cc3  .1........L.'...
00000410: a79c b66f 0299 6061 68d8 757e a0db d52f  ...o..`ah.u~.../
00000420: 4cb6 567e b4c1 53da c132 d928 ac24 c543  L.V~..S..2.(.$.C
00000430: 06ba b646 6758 1ab8 b830 6f5c 8c59 e613  ...FgX...0o\.Y..
00000440: 59ef 36eb 61d5 6ddc dcec 7ba2 2ef4 09b0  Y.6.a.m...{.....
00000450: d589 f43e 8cd8 a039 ed89 d867 2db6 1190  ...>...9...g-...
00000460: bae8 ae49 3f37 3c66 b5d0 dc6c a43d 6236  ...I?7<f...l.=b6
00000470: c9a2 769d a55c d580 3b15 1d87 65e7 530a  ..v..\..;...e.S.
00000480: bc2f 34e0 f06d 9dce cfcd 50dd bde2 6790  ./4..m....P...g.
00000490: 9f98 dfac 34fc ef49 7a8a ed29 fb2c ee29  ....4..Iz..).,.)
000004a0: 8728 577b edcb 965a e656 4abf 3583 1114  .(W{...Z.VJ.5...
000004b0: 1604 a2cb eeb9 1876 5537 1c20 94ec a74b  .......vU7. ...K
000004c0: 4dca 2130 aa72 749b dded bc58 8c11 45df  M.!0.rt....X..E.
000004d0: 8bd9 e8d6 dc37 ab5a c8a1 2f67 a28a 67b5  .....7.Z../g..g.
000004e0: 3d38 b61a 7db6 1422 8911 e898 780c cf73  =8..}.."....x..s
000004f0: 73c7 ebd4 9dfc 3cc0 7a37 3f26 5f26 4898  s.....<.z7?&_&H.
00000500: e4ab 3858 cb8e cbf3 70de d332 ff35 0f99  ..8X....p..2.5..
00000510: 433c 2b8d a21f 7ccb 8ed2 198e 417f ec03  C<+...|.....A...
00000520: aca8 4d9d 1397 452b 2b9c 5436 265e 5839  ..M...E++.T6&^X9
00000530: 5bd8 c390 d367 6de9 53cf 0105 fcb6 05fc  [....gm.S.......
00000540: bf9d cc89 a5a1 b65f ceb6 66b3 c82d 25e3  ......._..f..-%.
00000550: 1ab0 0e6d 18a6 5a51 4920 5148 8359 aca5  ...m..ZQI QH.Y..
00000560: fcf8 89b6 4603 ecfb 5422 a191 854d 0af4  ....F...T"...M..
00000570: 2a05 334e 8243 a92c 9342 5154 8d11 c667  *.3N.C.,.BQT...g
00000580: 621c 969b 5d24 ed67 c8a2 b256 22d6 1d52  b...]$.g...V"..R
00000590: 4faa cc29 abcc 62cb 768f e56d 55bc df4f  O..)..b.v..mU..O
000005a0: e61b 89c5 ecae 3527 eda8 a807 7590 fe3f  ......5'....u..?
000005b0: b6b0 6e28 c7dd 95c1 80dc a637 043f 0a5f  ..n(.......7.?._
000005c0: 1585 e201 63be 39eb d114 b457 4b7c 7b2e  ....c.9....WK|{.
000005d0: a3c6 44d0 943d 36d9 e3cc bcce 4646 9fea  ..D..=6.....FF..
000005e0: 83c4 e848 1bc2 08bc c97b 0f1c e2de ee8d  ...H.....{......
000005f0: 6298 b816 5fd8 ea9e 7c1e eae9 c219 14d8  b..._...|.......
00000600: 2201 3b95 fd84 089e 2618 e692 8f2a b953  ".;.....&....*.S
00000610: 428b 5831 8a11 692b b2a5 e895 79e3 0d86  B.X1..i+....y...
00000620: cbfc 12e5 e2e1 6beb fdca 9c1a df64 0875  ......k......d.u
00000630: 5fd0 dcb8 50f1 ee26 2f11 1fd8 6f71 5c1b  _...P..&/...oq\.
00000640: ede6 d8de 07ac 752e 9c38 fb87 702c ea46  ......u..8..p,.F
00000650: 4411 688e 394c 5859 fbf6 e83b fe4e ebc7  D.h.9LXY...;.N..
00000660: ef6a 8026 ffe4 c85e 7c1e d5d6 4395 93d4  .j.&...^|...C...
00000670: 882f c516 6f5e e1f8 e676 609c 27bf ddce  ./..o^...v`.'...
00000680: d939 aa5f f694 3dc6 d9be b849 d567 2e4f  .9._..=....I.g.O
00000690: 6ef9 4b63 f810 011b 7653 e4d3 116c a9de  n.Kc....vS...l..
000006a0: a987 009f 5084 fb2a 5506 3092 6246 13e5  ....P..*U.0.bF..
000006b0: 0a2d 4842 90a6 f76b 67f5 846f f5d4 76f4  .-HB...kg..o..v.
000006c0: 48dc 1610 aaa4 5ce4 9cbd bfef ea26 4237  H.....\......&B7
000006d0: 4e28 268a cd23 42a0 f648 256f 206c 79c1  N(&..#B..H%o ly.
000006e0: 7679 3c94 1332 062d 993d 7b13 c52e c071  vy<..2.-.={....q
000006f0: f247 c8b8 bef7 cf5a 3d18 e0b4 0af2 fbde  .G.....Z=.......
00000700: fcb7 5bc5 e7a4 dcb5 5992 892c e8e1 d9df  ..[.....Y..,....
00000710: 59b0 4099 4802 7885 555a e8be 76c0 6444  Y.@.H.x.UZ..v.dD
00000720: f936 9306 3d74 b4be 6967 e30d f155 ab0d  .6..=t..ig...U..
00000730: 636b 4c9e baad 4e85 af64 4ce9 dd3a 0999  ckL...N..dL..:..
00000740: 63e1 ce89 b086 221b 87ad 13cf f216 3f0b  c.....".......?.
00000750: 03b0 1004 955d 1177 2804 45cd 651b e2cf  .....].w(.E.e...
00000760: 5326 e3d6 3359 fd8a 2009 a98f c134 e9bd  S&..3Y.. ....4..
00000770: f202 168a 2b61 262f 171c ce69 442d 3d50  ....+a&/...iD-=P
00000780: 8ff5 7517 64db 7a04 fde6 18a2 a213 2ff9  ..u.d.z......./.
00000790: 8e21 800a 1b26 dd4f 390e f848 e597 99aa  .!...&.O9..H....
000007a0: 068a 78cf 1e2e a3e0 d92e eaa7 1b4b 4575  ..x..........KEu
000007b0: 423a 0d53 62ca 119f 8747 a636 9c86 bcb8  B:.Sb....G.6....
000007c0: 9046 e84e 84d1 3381 6235 6697 3103 4d83  .F.N..3.b5f.1.M.
000007d0: ed75 232e 7e74 96cc 1b2e 8492 bf67 e387  .u#.~t.......g..
000007e0: 41e8 3c69 9e70 f618 6c3a 0d6b ff4e 2955  A.<i.p..l:.k.N)U
000007f0: 2fec b8e3 3cbe 3679 b85a c84d a800 44b0  /...<.6y.Z.M..D.
00000800: ee21 fb8a a8be a0f1 f37a df88 4b00 d991  .!.......z..K...
00000810: 31cc b675 9e49 8498 6180 603b c53e b851  1..u.I..a.`;.>.Q
00000820: d8a9 7c33 071d 516f cd8e 25a6 ca4d fa5a  ..|3..Qo..%..M.Z
00000830: a1f4 b439 5cf1 ffa0 7f10 05c2 a6eb cfcf  ...9\...........
00000840: f935 12c8 d320 e98f 9bca 74f0 9deb 8878  .5... ....t....x
00000850: eef7 544f ccf9 2f08 54ed 5925 89dd 8547  ..TO../.T.Y%...G
00000860: e831 a472 a88d 0af7 4a6c d8e5 2b96 a2b1  .1.r....Jl..+...
00000870: 8e1f 1929 5b9d d5b1 d164 4e8f 7f5a df23  ...)[....dN..Z.#
00000880: 7e73 2a7a 0f86 6739 d671 79ce 1635 8249  ~s*z..g9.qy..5.I
00000890: d012 730d 2469 7b8f b01a 0135 217a 29f8  ..s.$i{....5!z).
000008a0: 1ca2 e64f 85f8 fc9b 4849 d4c9 a40b 5791  ...O....HI....W.
000008b0: d304 0bd6 67d9 5f35 6748 5f31 1985 bc11  ....g._5gH_1....
000008c0: 2b23 334f bb4f a1b7 9fad 8f51 eadf 61a0  +#3O.O.....Q..a.
000008d0: 2cc3 1047 986a 031e 0a58 c831 f93c bbc0  ,..G.j...X.1.<..
000008e0: ac4d 219a 96a2 fee1 fd3c 3192 2ed5 62e9  .M!......<1...b.
000008f0: 6dcb 0177 39ac 80c5 4ca8 c6be 7536 fbc9  m..w9...L...u6..
00000900: 1825 65d4 4f91 7c32 2652 09c6 67e6 7237  .%e.O.|2&R..g.r7
00000910: 8887 2ad9 ea1c 5064 e8b9 662e 4504 bbfa  ..*...Pd..f.E...
00000920: 8628 3850 58a8 6241 8477 7d0f 65b4 4b3b  .(8PX.bA.w}.e.K;
00000930: 0723 e354 049b 78eb 22cb 165d 9e3b f71a  .#.T..x."..].;..
00000940: a717 c3fd d5b4 b922 a620 8504 c37d efa8  .......". ...}..
00000950: d665 be14 a68c 4e46 f1c5 f312 bd27 8ac9  .e....NF.....'..
00000960: 35fb c197 adaa ca1e 2230 6003 b05c 72ed  5......."0`..\r.
00000970: ef2a 3ddf d3bb b6d8 ed2f 778c 5874 539a  .*=....../w.XtS.
00000980: 7f76 ce71 0adc c97b ab1f 5a34 0aed 3c36  .v.q...{..Z4..<6
00000990: 73d0 f1c9 753f 2976 570a a578 1573 70c0  s...u?)vW..x.sp.
000009a0: 758c 54c9 722b ac5d 6d8c dc95 923f 6617  u.T.r+.]m....?f.
000009b0: c511 2c0d 6375 3927 01db 26f1 e791 8321  ..,.cu9'..&....!
000009c0: 29fd 1003 ded5 61ff 5925 9701 e9b5 9307  ).....a.Y%......
000009d0: 2ae5 4b2b 3516 83c4 1858 18ad 675c 0042  *.K+5....X..g\.B
000009e0: 37d0 795d 3493 bc62 7a34 d52c 6592 e6f3  7.y]4..bz4.,e...
000009f0: bdf1 d5ee 04f8 890d 6769 ee5f ef90 7ef7  ........gi._..~.
00000a00: 9766 58a2 7f11 4685 5e56 5a3f aa21 1126  .fX...F.^VZ?.!.&
00000a10: 0a48 535a 3f73 17ea 71f5 78b8 39c4 1b59  .HSZ?s..q.x.9..Y
00000a20: 3986 77fd deaf 63c3 6d6d 3f7a b7da 167d  9.w...c.mm?z...}
00000a30: 9162 cf04 de50 00c8 2505 fae7 98f6 561f  .b...P..%.....V.
00000a40: 1b9b 3a94 793f 81ea 5917 7601 83c4 dea5  ..:.y?..Y.v.....
00000a50: 6be2 2ec7 6196 117e c65c 4cf8 4ff1 48e4  k...a..~.\L.O.H.
00000a60: 34f6 a035 8bf4 7be2 d4f6 3076 fca1 8495  4..5..{...0v....
00000a70: b58c 6d17 245f e29d 9636 68c6 4e59 9bf2  ..m.$_...6h.NY..
00000a80: 8c02 9a8c 3702 223b 0858 005e b08e 5acb  ....7.";.X.^..Z.
00000a90: 8651 5aae 458d 3dd5 36cb 4407 d678 1c59  .QZ.E.=.6.D..x.Y
00000aa0: 41c2 d89b 4adc c6b2 53fd 9663 ef4a 2a11  A...J...S..c.J*.
00000ab0: fdef 1bdf cd04 5ca0 8186 a9b7 0e40 b5d5  ......\......@..
00000ac0: 4a93 fd85 16a9 970e ca82 25e6 bdc7 1956  J.........%....V
00000ad0: ed82 b98c e1dc 5ad2 72a7 2fcb 90f5 8daa  ......Z.r./.....
00000ae0: 384a 88f3 26e2 b607 3d37 98b6 86e3 4b8e  8J..&...=7....K.
00000af0: baae cc39 a884 b87c a95b d54c 803a 132a  ...9...|.[.L.:.*
00000b00: edf9 00c4 e4f5 b7c3 7626 db82 e5da 68f6  ........v&....h.
00000b10: 898e 7f37 1760 8d87 0636 2b45 dbf5 b5c0  ...7.`...6+E....
00000b20: 61cf b5e4 1425 3f4d b9c1 af8e e10d 8564  a....%?M.......d
00000b30: f099 a3d4 97e5 c0b1 6662 ef78 6b91 c9ae  ........fb.xk...
00000b40: 3de1 7bdd 0957 6682 29a9 e11d 0e0a 85fd  =.{..Wf.).......
00000b50: 56f6 73e5 6347 0e60 5770 116b 03d1 7feb  V.s.cG.`Wp.k....
00000b60: bcbe 22a8 d917 b805 d42c fda7 5a68 ba5f  .."......,..Zh._
00000b70: 2ab3 49c9 9676 4125 0f54 6d42 0261 4a02  *.I..vA%.TmB.aJ.
00000b80: 9533 762a 870f 24c6 4d6c cc44 6e30 61dc  .3v*..$.Ml.Dn0a.
00000b90: 085e 8687 33b7 3454 796a 24bf 4953 5e70  .^..3.4Tyj$.IS^p
00000ba0: a2fb 1adb 86bd 90e9 b2d4 821d fa7c 971a  .............|..
00000bb0: 6fe1 b828 365c 1a15 7291 8504 b643 eb97  o..(6\..r....C..
00000bc0: a2b5 36a9 49fd 0ce5 5679 03ea d55b fd94  ..6.I...Vy...[..
00000bd0: 2da6 72bc 609f 2672 7164 d8d8 3537 cb20  -.r.`.&rqd..57. 
00000be0: 3bbb a7df c711 d506 b758 6e28 8451 78ea  ;........Xn(.Qx.
00000bf0: 3846 46dc f01a dfcb 87ed 5c37 cfd1 1566  8FF.......\7...f
00000c00: 0bdd e084 fba9 8c96 0f16 194b d44c 1d3f  ...........K.L.?
00000c10: 609f 2e94 ee08 d5b6 c7f6 1045 c9a3 e4ca  `..........E....
00000c20: b808 f369 2dbe bfb5 5462 4189 825f 14e7  ...i-...TbA.._..
00000c30: 4aea bc8d e01a 6a72 6cf2 0bea b700 90f8  J.....jrl.......
00000c40: 5fc2 7168 dc3f d86d 72f0 134d b97b 55eb  _.qh.?.mr..M.{U.
00000c50: 18c5 c5ba d574 aa83 e38f e883 a5d6 5192  .....t........Q.
00000c60: b56d dd08 5251 3a60 91fb 2663 0627 649f  .m..RQ:`..&c.'d.
00000c70: 1e3d adf8 e579 855a 8786 4f65 5f72 f487  .=...y.Z..Oe_r..
00000c80: 78a6 5c69 b4fb ee5f c1e9 2189 3c9b 7b20  x.\i..._..!.<.{ 
00000c90: 83ac 7044 ecfb e357 6093 8189 47a7 7d20  ..pD...W`...G.} 
00000ca0: c27c d018 0808 a3fd a01f 6b96 3f3c 1878  .|........k.?<.x
00000cb0: 2b0a 25a5 ed2f ce90 3e07 8e01 505c e34a  +.%../..>...P\.J
00000cc0: 721d 818a 56ef bf59 dede c722 6995 dd14  r...V..Y..."i...
00000cd0: c8c1 aa67 8dc8 aa84 1cba e268 450e de10  ...g.......hE...
00000ce0: 03ad 3614 fa40 631e 8da4 219a f1b2 62dd  ..6..@c...!...b.
00000cf0: 761d 2475 5ebe a135 1dd1 c5d3 c7f8 bb41  v.$u^..5.......A
00000d00: c3fe d4e1 f2e3 8531 4b71 dfc7 c7e8 c35d  .......1Kq.....]
00000d10: 97eb 81db 9ee6 5da2 b5e2 7eef 971a 45c1  ......]...~...E.
00000d20: 0dfa 0cf4 c38a 7454 92a6 0efb 7d7e d2f8  ......tT....}~..
00000d30: 0119 76be 4045 0964 8c66 ecbd 2164 1ab3  ..v.@E.d.f..!d..
00000d40: 106c 9863 da42 ecd2 d69f 0ca2 4ee4 46fa  .l.c.B......N.F.
00000d50: 54e4 e138 8859 edb9 241c 87ca 59c3 c6f8  T..8.Y..$...Y...
00000d60: f8b5 3ab4 e162 8958 7d64 d629 5ed0 9c84  ..:..b.X}d.)^...
00000d70: 803c aad8 f5fe 4d29 1d0b f34c 9de1 7af0  .<....M)...L..z.
00000d80: 1678 f2c4 8e8a e186 f981 42b4 8e43 8eb1  .x........B..C..
00000d90: 2270 6776 8ec5 1f19 30de 4a26 3fc8 caab  "pgv....0.J&?...
00000da0: ce8f 9657 307c 5405 e2b7 c8f9 299f 23eb  ...W0|T.....).#.
00000db0: 3763 12f9 b356 00a4 5ca0 e3de a071 5703  7c...V..\....qW.
00000dc0: 2bb9 2183 41f8 d729 a68c 3881 cdb4 f7bd  +.!.A..)..8.....
00000dd0: 2639 da18 617d 92a4 6faa ad3d 3370 e31e  &9..a}..o..=3p..
00000de0: 73a0 d841 083d e44b f913 9cce b5cd 0a11  s..A.=.K........
00000df0: 9bd8 8089 d732 7ca0 a084 d0ac ccef 6cbd  .....2|.......l.
00000e00: 58bd ee0a 5875 5645 7de6 bdb3 5fcb 0d80  X...XuVE}..._...
00000e10: aef2 d247 74f3 8526 9eb3 333a 70bf f5bb  ...Gt..&..3:p...
00000e20: 2a79 1b5b 8675 1a78 f997 148a 235c e73c  *y.[.u.x....#\.<
00000e30: bab4 56b1 0d6e cae8 a7d8 7d26 6216 4ff6  ..V..n....}&b.O.
00000e40: c9bb b471 7923 9751 cba0 443e 6239 21d4  ...qy#.Q..D>b9!.
00000e50: 4f00 56a8 61ec a392 fca1 cb13 d322 9815  O.V.a........"..
00000e60: 8a29 e6af 0208 a170 bc87 5ec7 d5c2 5697  .).....p..^...V.
00000e70: 0592 ed66 c4e7 74e1 0ff6 9145 6e23 eed6  ...f..t....En#..
00000e80: aead 2769 40c8 b1e0 3184 4e22 0714 bd91  ..'i@...1.N"....
00000e90: ada4 c868 e48d 9ab0 159d b356 975e c37b  ...h.......V.^.{
00000ea0: ea92 5142 da0c 5d12 8595 2adb 3574 54af  ..QB..]...*.5tT.
00000eb0: 622f b71d aa24 75d8 b9f9 bbc8 1046 6d2c  b/...$u......Fm,
00000ec0: ca92 d60f 9080 8885 5a7e 9b79 46d9 3fb5  ........Z~.yF.?.
00000ed0: e5fc 24d8 fb6e 9b0c bb15 094d f801 1a51  ..$..n.....M...Q
00000ee0: 8397 1c52 909f 074a 39f2 ffd4 d95b cc0f  ...R...J9....[..
00000ef0: ec53 9e85 f4a7 6665 5e77 8b64 66c6 8541  .S....fe^w.df..A
00000f00: 37fa 740e d842 6b27 3d3e 2bc1 5afa 0c07  7.t..Bk'=>+.Z...
00000f10: 8e7e 2f60 4a6a 49f1 eb8d f16d 0409 ba39  .~/`JjI....m...9
00000f20: ead1 1f3f c718 6c7c a213 527d 252a 4358  ...?..l|..R}%*CX
00000f30: f6aa 50b0 c485 b96e e1c0 8a5a 20eb d8cb  ..P....n...Z ...
00000f40: a443 379a 1ad3 0f36 b275 081c 9278 82d6  .C7....6.u...x..
00000f50: 6177 59ce 4a12 9658 5d18 3d22 8f6d dbf5  awY.J..X].=".m..
00000f60: e531 e0de e7d0 7657 d619 622c b8a3 fc25  .1....vW..b,...%
00000f70: deb3 92d3 0342 d1d4 56e9 5aa8 6858 0d90  .....B..V.Z.hX..
00000f80: 04c3 19c0 d83b 4862 8d1f df76 d10b 4eae  .....;Hb...v..N.
00000f90: c6a6 9536 a4eb 9d51 e446 e021 e970 a5ad  ...6...Q.F.!.p..
00000fa0: c5c7 9d8b 4eac eb55 be16 800c 65bb 1af6  ....N..U....e...
00000fb0: 0a5b f5a2 79d4 6e26 c399 a584 c048 f267  .[..y.n&.....H.g
00000fc0: e5b9 f785 8fba c8af 2e44 22c4 85ef 2234  .........D"..."4
00000fd0: b16c 62e2 c323 9264 a561 d332 5a95 7477  .lb..#.d.a.2Z.tw
00000fe0: 70cc 5756 8381 87c3 78f6 eb10 a3c0 f768  p.WV....x......h
00000ff0: 678a 6acf 671d 0615 5c78 02fa c5ce 6491  g.j.g...\x....d.
00001000: 2ceb ad3f fba9 8fc2 b9ec a053 af52 168d  ,..?.......S.R..
00001010: 0096 5f17 1e11 ae59 b4e8 c9b8 e0f2 579c  .._....Y......W.
00001020: 8d38 fb76 80e6 bb19 515a a4cc dbd3 99cb  .8.v....QZ......
00001030: 3ad5 7622 b0b2 4db4 2acd 0564 8fa1 9e61  :.v"..M.*..d...a
00001040: 735f 4516 4909 5b58 647c 5156 d074 0048  s_E.I.[Xd|QV.t.H
00001050: c2e0 5f1d 3b11 13f6 17a5 9dae 6cae 317f  .._.;.......l.1.
00001060: b0f1 1237 7384 8f1f e651 086c 5656 d7e5  ...7s....Q.lVV..
00001070: 3b9c efa2 ab19 973a 5333 f20a fd95 c773  ;......:S3.....s
00001080: 70b8 ccbb 403a d6ad 1016 5271 b09d d886  p...@:....Rq....
00001090: f939 8e7e affa 6fcb 95d6 7075 12ea a5f4  .9.~..o...pu....
000010a0: c8b8 c994 7f85 ebe6 6c5e 09cc 3603 a06e  ........l^..6..n
000010b0: 2362 1df5 347f 4a30 976e e59a dc80 ff6d  #b..4.J0.n.....m
000010c0: b3cf 25f0 9fc5 761d d94f 30d0 80cf ba09  ..%...v..O0.....
000010d0: 04fd 21b2 d501 4dee bf62 76a3 6128 5f5f  ..!...M..bv.a(__
000010e0: cfeb 3e02 b997 18c9 2b97 413d c4e0 c9da  ..>.....+.A=....
000010f0: bc4c c3a0 432a 89f7 12bf 2780 0f71 18a8  .L..C*....'..q..
00001100: d9bd 0aae 9d1c a27a f2fc 0eb7 1329 a2ac  .......z.....)..
00001110: b255 64fb 4e45 b1d8 a5aa 5629 fff1 5e41  .Ud.NE....V)..^A
00001120: 4e6e 0350 78e0 ebb4 a338 2eae 4bdf b3b9  Nn.Px....8..K...
00001130: 9685 3059 0559 bd21 dc79 5b57 d6c6 14f4  ..0Y.Y.!.y[W....
00001140: c08e 5a38 becc b01e 73ba a384 f013 d43c  ..Z8....s......<
00001150: 3947 f118 abe6 5a99 655f e422 56ed 800c  9G....Z.e_."V...
00001160: e383 60d0 8f6e 9c00 2d9e f754 87b3 ce23  ..`..n..-..T...#
00001170: 089b ac19 163f f5cc e4c8 264d d01f 4bfb  .....?....&M..K.
00001180: 2575 e365 1a4f ba14 63d6 e0f1 af7b a428  %u.e.O..c....{.(
00001190: 630a 6a46 c93b bd0f 1a65 3116 480f 7901  c.jF.;...e1.H.y.
000011a0: b406 5f2a 5175 06b2 fe83 52cc 8daf 00fe  .._*Qu....R.....
000011b0: feb4 02c6 c2c2 d00e 1b5d 6a8d b640 3670  .........]j..@6p
000011c0: 4c58 22a3 d020 6911 d88f 71cb c6cd 6898  LX".. i...q...h.
000011d0: d7b7 78c5 3d90 f186 4572 4e27 841f 1aa5  ..x.=...ErN'....
000011e0: b959 ebbe 9919 a2eb 2273 fa82 64f3 53f4  .Y......"s..d.S.
000011f0: e3a3 d7c0 e6e2 cc59 c81c 9f59 78b6 b64a  .......Y...Yx..J
00001200: 287f b836 83a0 7474 76cb c7c9 a536 41cb  (..6..ttv....6A.
00001210: f559 667f fb9d d700 3a86 2979 81e3 26fd  .Yf.....:.)y..&.
00001220: d08c acad 90c4 b62a 27fd 727d d312 2ede  .......*'.r}....
00001230: 5788 f85d edab 2659 e209 9313 9279 a183  W..]..&Y.....y..
00001240: 7baa 7bb1 63a2 72a6 77d6 14e6 d928 863b  {.{.c.r.w....(.;
00001250: 5860 4120 3d4e 8b85 b46f be2d c8d3 f415  X`A =N...o.-....
00001260: 2079 527f 133d 1ea0 fe04 8ea8 ef63 2684   yR..=.......c&.
00001270: fd66 49c2 1e2c d19c b6cc 1698 d8c2 ad54  .fI..,.........T
00001280: 2f9f 5b0d e76f c5f2 6f2f e7ee 2cdc a764  /.[..o..o/..,..d
00001290: a689 8111 5fb2 8c75 6335 1661 5f39 dcab  ...._..uc5.a_9..
000012a0: ed18 255d e1a2 8118 d8f5 2e98 d13c 8134  ..%].........<.4
000012b0: d09e 4324 f465 1b3a fedc d262 9c5f 838c  ..C$.e.:...b._..
000012c0: 059d 8475 7672 faee c9d8 650f e691 7439  ...uvr....e...t9
000012d0: 2ddb 9942 100e 8834 5fc3 81ef 94fe dd25  -..B...4_......%
000012e0: c427 74a9 cf51 1cc8 5848 368a 0559 101a  .'t..Q..XH6..Y..
000012f0: 1383 817a 0a2b cd3d e680 1f54 0523 7529  ...z.+.=...T.#u)
00001300: 120c 94e5 dc96 ccce 3d88 4d91 464e 7abd  ........=.M.FNz.
00001310: 1585 d961 c8bc 09a3 0a50 cfaa 0c1c 7f3c  ...a.....P.....<
00001320: a52e fc01 3f37 cd03 6b34 d4da fb3d a20a  ....?7..k4...=..
00001330: fdae 7201 3e0f 81eb 0997 8072 4d8e be11  ..r.>......rM...
00001340: 3867 7d25 a052 d318 e702 474c 95b6 721d  8g}%.R....GL..r.
00001350: 3730 40a5 75b6 be42 72c8 00c3 4b4c 9e1d  70@.u..Br...KL..
00001360: 3c5b c7e8 8ed3 2473 bde5 f1c3 0905 b883  <[....$s........
00001370: 681c 7c04 9e4d c0dc 3579 b49f d01d 60d6  h.|..M..5y....`.
00001380: c984 d2f5 9df8 0011 13e9 c37c aa77 765f  ...........|.wv_
00001390: 0a41 83f4 4ea6 0a9a 54d8 72d6 f6b7 aa69  .A..N...T.r....i
000013a0: 8b9e 5cb7 2d7e 7eba 4a52 57a6 dc1b b33d  ..\.-~~.JRW....=
000013b0: fbe7 d8e0 b1e9 09d0 ceca 8214 53e3 eb5b  ............S..[
000013c0: 4ad3 9f71 b075 e9e1 8e2f 3977 c33d 698b  J..q.u.../9w.=i.
000013d0: 226d 7901 a2f2 18f3 610d 12fb eb5e 5216  "my.....a....^R.
000013e0: b347 426a bef1 11df 006c c597 c7e7 eaa8  .GBj.....l......
000013f0: ff99 ef1c fa15 aad2 c102 6ae0 a889 a8b6  ..........j.....
00001400: 75af e695 ab24 5408 b8cd cad8 a016 491a  u....$T.......I.
00001410: 4afa d35f ab51 746b 3747 706a 723a e2b3  J.._.Qtk7Gpjr:..
00001420: cdb0 cdfc 40ee 4544 58e6 9e7c 09b3 89f4  ....@.EDX..|....
00001430: bbc3 3f0a af0c 4e15 2fe5 72fd 7212 c521  ..?...N./.r.r..!
00001440: fd8d 33d7 5631 6ee4 0eb1 93f7 668d dae3  ..3.V1n.....f...
00001450: c6e3 f136 0514 5e96 8670 109c 93db 79d4  ...6..^..p....y.
00001460: 63eb 415f ef36 437c 96b1 c157 5bec 648c  c.A_.6C|...W[.d.
00001470: 89b8 e7da ad18 ae5b 4a5d 8419 3824 5210  .......[J]..8$R.
00001480: 22b5 cbcc 69dc 2e27 da0d 3324 1e83 245a  "...i..'..3$..$Z
00001490: 7127 ffd4 f87c 13a2 25bc 320d 85e9 5da5  q'...|..%.2...].
000014a0: 4c39 056e 8806 e903 8dad b1ed b636 8abe  L9.n.........6..
000014b0: 1006 43ab 518c 49a9 b349 e2ef 3471 8b1b  ..C.Q.I..I..4q..
000014c0: d1f9 ade6 e66c a3ec d7cf 7207 baca 2819  .....l....r...(.
000014d0: c3d7 92dc 7c36 e0b0 afc3 d124 37c2 e01b  ....|6.....$7...
000014e0: a7a8 1440 59cf f768 aa87 5ddb 3015 f5bd  ...@Y..h..].0...
000014f0: 6017 df6f 1b7b 6f13 1bf7 fe73 54a6 2746  `..o.{o....sT.'F
00001500: 8728 879b 9c2b 7eb7 d6ac 1916 5ba6 ef0c  .(...+~.....[...
00001510: b44a 03cf 1c89 44f9 f00d 9e0d 5cd9 daae  .J....D.....\...
00001520: f341 bcf5 7dba b67a 3771 5cc2 a9e4 c801  .A..}..z7q\.....
00001530: 41d7 c31a b807 5799 b938 52eb 8ef5 06cd  A.....W..8R.....
00001540: 569f 99e5 78cb 91aa 6d9c d836 7cd0 56be  V...x...m..6|.V.
00001550: b37f 7078 ad35 db1d c4a0 94eb 1011 130f  ..px.5..........
00001560: f282 4b61 fca2 42a0 e095 0593 0611 5f2f  ..Ka..B......._/
00001570: 9dde 8c63 e9ee d6e9 ff6c 8f34 8533 ec82  ...c.....l.4.3..
00001580: eab3 8104 1b87 6ad9 051b 51d4 9531 bf73  ......j...Q..1.s
00001590: e4a7 d21f b723 0695 ed80 92b9 04c2 33b3  .....#........3.
000015a0: 03f4 d0a9 3e5d e168 21c1 cbeb 01ae ce6c  ....>].h!......l
000015b0: 441d 1e53 9044 d92e d57a fabe 91a5 61a6  D..S.D...z....a.
000015c0: 83f0 f1cf 5caf 67a3 cc2e e4f2 0be1 7075  ....\.g.......pu
000015d0: 51b9 4227 7ad7 9cb0 b0f0 31b7 8cb7 e1d5  Q.B'z.....1.....
000015e0: 4f16 6a12 bd22 5d59 485d 56b2 97e3 a7cb  O.j.."]YH]V.....
000015f0: 85bb a821 bf3b f0fe 395d 8ae2 baaf d82c  ...!.;..9].....,
00001600: 64af db13 ddee 49f7 1d73 438c 36f4 1d48  d.....I..sC.6..H
00001610: 792a 9fe1 f67b 85ad c8f1 faf0 ab52 9b99  y*...{.......R..
00001620: 2189 22ed 8176 de39 8c75 bdb2 357f 1a65  !."..v.9.u..5..e
00001630: 366d abf8 460a 8c2e fb11 7057 84e2 5fa8  6m..F.....pW.._.
00001640: 6c2c 8349 b0ca 621c 3d89 680c ed82 4d9c  l,.I..b.=.h...M.
00001650: ecc3 9d9d c0ae a4a3 d8bb 980e 9fd5 937f  ................
00001660: b4ea 799c a059 9220 7776 a9d4 d11a cb5b  ..y..Y. wv.....[
00001670: d787 4c74 8952 fde8 ec65 9aeb 85cc 7fe1  ..Lt.R...e......
00001680: 2b89 e954 a599 f1d0 cb3e f1d8 cd26 d490  +..T.....>...&..
00001690: 192b 14ba 2fc0 3167 2bf8 fdaa 66c3 8744  .+../.1g+...f..D
000016a0: 9cf2 b3d7 5859 e046 9438 2644 e73c f70b  ....XY.F.8&D.<..
000016b0: cab9 f982 02e6 1b44 1a06 0382 122e 8727  .......D.......'
000016c0: c56c b717 82ef 0274 cf18 010b 8c5e 0b08  .l.....t.....^..
000016d0: 7e42 53fb 0f44 3ae6 57ad 8405 d7e5 88ba  ~BS..D:.W.......
000016e0: 4fd3 2cf2 6695 9f37 1499 5d9c bc52 399c  O.,.f..7..]..R9.
000016f0: ed30 75c1 8b3e 48da 9e89 b259 dd7e 570c  .0u..>H....Y.~W.
00001700: 760b 1b00 54fc fd3c e3ad bfaf 1b22 d60e  v...T..<....."..
00001710: 178e fc6b b3ff 32e1 c9db 0b59 a6e2 55f5  ...k..2....Y..U.
00001720: 6d5e 11c9 da20 befd f01e 01da cf16 87ac  m^... ..........
00001730: cd39 8d04 1233 4960 fe97 4e64 aa6d 4024  .9...3I`..Nd.m@$
00001740: e6bb f9e4 750d c47f 1ec7 1133 c8e6 f972  ....u......3...r
00001750: daf5 0794 3c7f 1892 9b7e 5331 0214 b26f  ....<....~S1...o
00001760: 50c6 a38d 134e fd13 6456 1cd6 c3ec 38d3  P....N..dV....8.
00001770: e4e8 1690 afa5 8f78 27d3 1c13 dd5d 4c53  .......x'....]LS
00001780: e309 e6c0 7b7c 7cc6 482d c44f 7048 5e46  ....{||.H-.OpH^F
00001790: ea34 791c a65f cb1c ade9 024e 3b66 0ee1  .4y.._.....N;f..
000017a0: 6f82 abf3 5245 1181 e153 984e 76cc b29c  o...RE...S.Nv...
000017b0: 1d0e de93 0e86 624c 8ecb 9c8e 42cd c389  ......bL....B...
000017c0: b113 cf6d ee0c 24bd 524d 929b 386f db46  ...m..$.RM..8o.F
000017d0: bb6c 4d33 7ece 1f83 3059 819d d6e5 45d3  .lM3~...0Y....E.
000017e0: 9800 713b fee1 740b 6775 49ae c2b5 07b7  ..q;..t.guI.....
000017f0: efa2 e3d4 79f3 f776 7938 5b8f c25a 7ff3  ....y..vy8[..Z..
00001800: 2070 1dad 24a0 4602 42f4 4e32 06bb 3392   p..$.F.B.N2..3.
00001810: cfa8 e4d0 cd93 db48 807b cac3 dc3f a07e  .......H.{...?.~
00001820: c19f 88f1 7cad 10d7 4e47 a04c f6ae dc03  ....|...NG.L....
00001830: 28f9 4cdd 26e3 fb28 ed1c 66cd e699 71fd  (.L.&..(..f...q.
00001840: c5f0 90d9 c533 e776 6821 e5aa 4afb 73e1  .....3.vh!..J.s.
00001850: bcf9 ffcc 86c7 6453 9856 969b f93d 7d3d  ......dS.V...=}=
00001860: dbc1 82de 8856 590a 1472 5150 22d7 66b0  .....VY..rQP".f.
00001870: 9c14 0e95 c081 5211 d2d1 1cc2 3dd7 8f7e  ......R.....=..~
00001880: d7e3 57ac 30d5 7ae2 05c0 ec94 2c0f 9a0a  ..W.0.z.....,...
00001890: 1c02 c058 c5df de40 be4f df3a 6cbd 4dec  ...X...@.O.:l.M.
000018a0: 042a ba3c 221d 2e6c aa36 9c8d b764 f6aa  .*.<"..l.6...d..
000018b0: 49d5 5297 711c 0c26 40f8 31be 3c5e d058  I.R.q..&@.1.<^.X
000018c0: 4364 433c 08e0 8100 84f8 ffc7 3dce 8e5a  CdC<........=..Z
000018d0: 1169 5b05 1b5e 277c 69f7 8755 4492 e8de  .i[..^'|i..UD...
000018e0: c2d6 6ca3 86e0 4c66 286a f5bf f608 c726  ..l...Lf(j.....&
000018f0: 79c6 89df 093c 90bc a654 df0e aff8 efe5  y....<...T......
00001900: a409 2f4e 5337 d002 3bac 035c fb37 ba0c  ../NS7..;..\.7..
00001910: 7043 f3d1 ac9a ce96 8fff aaab 2039 d88a  pC.......... 9..
00001920: 979b ae52 fb68 a1df 94e1 f204 9d2e 672a  ...R.h........g*
00001930: 255a a721 10d4 df13 df7c d2df 4474 5c46  %Z.!.....|..Dt\F
00001940: 223d f360 ecb7 ae9f f017 219a 22f7 8103  "=.`......!."...
00001950: 62f1 a171 5d52 6666 301c 93c8 2267 17d5  b..q]Rff0..."g..
00001960: f20d c368 1a55 1441 733f 57e2 c8ba 44bf  ...h.U.As?W...D.
00001970: d6dc 9886 6c2b fb78 5746 03bf e3cd 45e0  ....l+.xWF....E.
00001980: 146a a5d4 9e3f 38e7 b9e8 0db7 8376 8135  .j...?8......v.5
00001990: e7ed 98d2 acec 2668 5ed7 0516 ca80 c3cd  ......&h^.......
000019a0: e336 702f e877 42ee 9efe cb4f 9cfb a371  .6p/.wB....O...q
000019b0: bdda 6104 2723 4f18 5533 18a3 1f56 e66e  ..a.'#O.U3...V.n
000019c0: c3f1 2dae b72f b7d6 b266 36d0 80b1 821e  ..-../...f6.....
000019d0: 3426 fd3f 4170 241e 1e04 5aeb febd cdf9  4&.?Ap$...Z.....
000019e0: d63a 897c ad52 011b 59bc a2a6 d174 0da5  .:.|.R..Y....t..
000019f0: de80 f9bd 187c 4e1b 36b5 4aca d8c0 2746  .....|N.6.J...'F
00001a00: ac0d 84f8 c0fa 9fbb bece 7be0 9db5 b427  ..........{....'
00001a10: da48 1284 42af 0c30 7738 577c b4b3 f5b6  .H..B..0w8W|....
00001a20: c528 0b27 0cd1 a674 93c4 9b3d ca3c 3853  .(.'...t...=.<8S
00001a30: 7ac1 1182 9fd7 2038 77b6 759c 1bda e211  z..... 8w.u.....
00001a40: fb78 7b7f 28dc df90 26f6 cc5c 9faa b29e  .x{.(...&..\....
00001a50: a570 b8bd 6e0d 5976 f5cc 2d27 85f0 027e  .p..n.Yv..-'...~
00001a60: 8434 3259 0801 2598 c311 a255 8e78 aa74  .42Y..%....U.x.t
00001a70: 38e4 6acf 432b 1b40 1679 542d af3a a302  8.j.C+.@.yT-.:..
00001a80: 2521 07e4 52ae 6817 2b32 fd8a 12aa 306b  %!..R.h.+2....0k
00001a90: bb9d a807 6dad 8e0e e3e4 2925 51ce 8f0a  ....m.....)%Q...
00001aa0: 218c cc83 355b f867 39ef 3873 58fc 16a1  !...5[.g9.8sX...
00001ab0: a9d7 92a1 3c20 334b c292 fa55 0652 6685  ....< 3K...U.Rf.
00001ac0: 28eb 41b5 94d5 56fc 6ff3 f22a 68db 3d17  (.A...V.o..*h.=.
00001ad0: c7dc b5f1 23f3 dc58 ec85 d151 01d0 83aa  ....#..X...Q....
00001ae0: e4fa 2746 29f8 b815 4322 9d40 4e38 bdbf  ..'F)...C".@N8..
00001af0: 012b b28c f418 8e30 1694 48f1 542b dbcb  .+.....0..H.T+..
00001b00: 2c7a 8148 6b72 f144 9255 a4d4 4d4f 9217  ,z.Hkr.D.U..MO..
00001b10: 94e5 8969 60b0 d37d ff52 ef96 d070 1b01  ...i`..}.R...p..
00001b20: 496d 1f6d 5b97 5760 c1e5 2f75 4f83 59fc  Im.m[.W`../uO.Y.
00001b30: a4b5 231b af5e 00d3 b951 95f6 5686 4ff3  ..#..^...Q..V.O.
00001b40: 1424 31db b56b 7876 427b 9f0c 73f9 a64b  .$1..kxvB{..s..K
00001b50: 52c7 36ec ebaf a4b1 7057 8fc2 d8a8 40e9  R.6.....pW....@.
00001b60: 39c4 fb45 c3b3 6a27 245f 50f3 75e9 271c  9..E..j'$_P.u.'.
00001b70: 4841 4fb2 aa87 a624 badd 94c8 6fda fe3b  HAO....$....o..;
00001b80: e4aa 8e73 aea1 d9b8 80e1 223f 057f eeb7  ...s......"?....
00001b90: 8be6 8dbc a540 be28 ea5b d26b 87b8 c7a5  .....@.(.[.k....
00001ba0: d1d1 148c c748 c157 fb20 1b41 cbfa b63d  .....H.W. .A...=
00001bb0: f378 94a2 93d1 63cf b35e b255 90a3 5ff8  .x....c..^.U.._.
00001bc0: 2956 3aaa 9364 b7c2 4c17 81f6 aeed d95f  )V:..d..L......_
00001bd0: 0fc1 b7a6 ffa9 fff4 0f1d 30e3 3b44 3b48  ..........0.;D;H
00001be0: e15e 85e2 e997 b0dc febe bae4 528d 660c  .^..........R.f.
00001bf0: e8fb f21f 2a0e 3615 053d dee0 9423 6d5b  ....*.6..=...#m[
00001c00: 8602 b320 4bca 1e4b 98d1 0cef 730e 8e6a  ... K..K....s..j
00001c10: d684 6592 1db0 8361 9e46 b234 10f2 942d  ..e....a.F.4...-
00001c20: acd4 a96f 6894 00a8 68cd 4e56 ecaf bbfc  ...oh...h.NV....
00001c30: 3f3d 9abb 0419 8caa 5781 d942 965c 1396  ?=......W..B.\..
00001c40: 7581 e4bf 4157 1bb1 7d86 6e86 24e9 c59e  u...AW..}.n.$...
00001c50: e147 402e 0069 45b6 24d6 1a47 83e6 e2ba  .G@..iE.$..G....
00001c60: fb09 7f12 13ce ae0b dcd7 83e6 086a 4100  .............jA.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [///](https://esolangs.org/wiki////), 14256 bytes

```
/Q/\/\///0/A8Q"/!UQ'/C2GQ?/5AQ>/@@Q</U6Q./6GQ,/ACQ`/AGQ:/CGQ;/C#Q|/8AQ=/C8Q+/8CQ_/AUQ-/GUQ)/GCQ(/C7Q*/8GQ&/UCQ^/CUQ%/GAQ$/G7Q#/UGQ@/CAQ!/UAQ~/GGQ9/CCQ8/UUQ7/AAQ1/88Q2/77Q3/9CQ4/~GQ5/8UQ6/7A/06~?!983A~U7C69797C5C%U^C*!%&#8^^6C$C52&##U~;U@^C~;@#=`#@^@:@G"787U7^7|;&G8%@~A@C%-7^:&!&+#@~;=,~5C-9G#*@G9%U@U@G>&!~5C-94##A9G6~U7%U~A%G9*U3U~5(C%G2>C-97^@G5G9#1A@~+)%:#^:!C-~C5~A%^9-~A~A~&8_@%~@:&7@&86%U~@C*U~=`!$G*2A~:1G9&7=$@G3!##8@&6:+~A#^C$;@9U@U~U@#8_~8%G^~!G@$^C$~@8@G!C~&G!-~#A%@=~#U9*U3U@#U4:6!9A-~=A9G(~+++-7$C~U7<~`^~U~9A!G|C~:9%U^6-@5%=A~C%C%)8~@;_9|#7%1(G2^~7@^6@!G@-~#|3G#7^@#:#A)87C~A4G@!@^C)!#&%U7(C+#U~3#_~C!3&8%G#@86%9+!G@:#^~<)8@#@C5-9$(^~,?8%@^7%4G#!!;;9G#7@#`@#6*=~!@C~7:+#2%)!#7*@%@91G6868~C.65%@98(U4$#U961G!538689_7&7%C!8(974*2G2A)8%U~C5_4!$+%&#&"9`*C-@96#7#(96##95(^^@#7G##_@*U~#6=@U~@%C4C%1G8.9,*C$1-~@;A$5%^6$~#9,!C*U~|=A3C2#;*82?*U9`@#U@(8@$G!~A9#`@!G&*9$!9_7#7U^~C*29A++-74U~&G@C!*95~A~;##8^=A#8~*9_7(G##9!8489A:#C!)G^7@!~*U79A!@~#*8~A$~89$~&87#A(9+*6!^92A%G.&7@&7!*8~#,56=7#7%%&G9A|1~@&1&#=9A(G#C1-~6;#6~5~0_.@+6C6*8$U9#U~U71.|C2~2G^27~#9U~7!8~#7@G6&7!;A-9&?#@5G@U@%~;^:#*!C%&71^3G@^C*6;^C2+##:#1A@$~9)"7(!C!%U~75>G!8@;A%^@8%#C!#A#8>&#A5~C!^7(&!G*U7U~9!@|@~U~#*8@G8%C+G@-~^7^7@&5~@;?#2A^C63-98%8~=$%$G57~7~#!%G5=A%%C~846*865_^(9##C*#6*&~U~,6*U@9##C6~687~A%G#8@%@+57)*<<1U~C5G##;A^C"@|8~U~`^6=.98$?~#6@5-@:@^C64A*!@G.##86U9A%$G6^~9!^@#9U^2G3'6|&+|%4`6@=3A@$G#87@%~7G*&*2^~#A?(9A|$(9!C!G#7)#8$G^90~8~!@9`5G!87C4=A#*^:6&6%>G2G!;#3*@9U7!#_~U7C6(!98>^C6~C~#@97C6~|C1~#A#A@;#A!$G#(~|(%G##7"@C1$=%#6~0%U.!=7#A$G#^;9!!@G8$^C~!@$-6#`+G9##*U~@%#;U@U2,5G(9`!&#7|=A@9A^4@8%?%#A-~`"~C!@!C!=A5%#A-^~#`568~=>!#!*+5C!3U9A%#A~A#7$$~#A*#7$$%G5%G9A&7^(!#`"~!;7%#A|97~<95~75~#9,+#;^=(9#7$%G($$%8~|%#A#A!G&7C6;8~&7(%C~@G#A~A(U@%(C!C!+6(*8%~8(9&7|%%U~7=A@9`*8@%C!8$G#7!G1A-~|52=A;A(#!!@82A#@%@*U~7$G^2A~U297@-~*87#@G97#?986@U~A~A~#*@~`986U7~C!^7(#9A#(G8$&#A#A|@!)!^7U~A9A=6-4U~!G*#17)~A@(&*^6@;&8@#*&~36#87C6~#7%@8(C+87%G#=A#217U@G@C$G+!C*@9A|8_@G^~!1U~#;A3!!@+57%G5G#!%!;+G@C6#&!=A)#&5%U2_^C!#,6C*5()1U~6#7%G#2G(G8$C2%&)#A%89<%~7G87G9A5_7;6-698@G8$@%G2(%#_7G2&6)*#8$$G|((^^~7G6^7G89U>G2C*|C?!8%@87U~(&8@U9A%+#9A^C*|G#A@8%@U@C5=.6%#^9A!!!-4#A#*8(%4#17;;U~|!9!^2A~^~U~@C!;6#C!)G6)5%G2G#97@%(|"79A=A34U@456U~|@;!%~A~C6%@G#=2`#U2G#91A@+!9A&!8_^^7#A$G(G6+8~7;5=~75)%G6#C*>#@$G6@C)687#9#&##U~6^.9A!G5(C!!@)-6"74!82!(%4#U~8%8_~#C!%1,1A@9A-2(;!)-@=A&7>=7C%U^6#6^C*|(#9A=~C!#U7>U~=65~7$)#^C~!!#A%U^^C.#9A)!@G5;5=@9#A#;|@)G"7U~|&|C++8^2@9#7$@1A*69_^@C*^~89!<%8~U9!8^~A(&!@(C!~!!$5=7%%~#_2G#!!|@C!-7U9!9A@89A9!%U~#7G8_@95%(&87%@C+5C5%%$G#A~,!87~#?(@G!%(@879U9A@:(G*U~A@#&7#A@"~A(@G5~U97=A5~_~A)#A#|^2U29U@U78>#7~U2@1A#1A9U7#A#A@^C!:#8%~C1%G!C!9A@(;_9!G1^4!~!@#U@G@86U>^2A-~6!3A(G87U~57C+!86U4@%U7(;|&*9A;@*87@^97C6!%G8$G57U9A9#^C!(%#=A|@%G(4^~#7)#^7C1G#@=A&|G9!;U7U7%@G!~#`|~#A#|%G6(#`|C*5(@#97?%+*C2%G&8$C-~##U2C*U~A(@G@%(3874#!$)#|#!@U4>C5=A#7(57G6~#8@%!9*!:#U~<()!C2!&!G!(@~A-@91G|#A#U@G@9A9#^@G!#7=7G@U~!@5,*#C!G#`!@^~U7|9`#U~U@C!<@"7=^.6C5G!*@!%C~#C?=,6-9U@$!C6~U9!|C~A#1C!C.2@G|@((9_29`|=_68~_~#*5G!@G68%3U7G8~A(|8_7G6%(+|5>%G(978%&*!96979A"96:()+%U717G5G!##_7!&65)#A#A569`87^~8_7G69#=(%%)8.|@1U3#A=6U~#A#U~U~C!8%8_6@C!>3&17G6~`^6*|@<9!*5~@#87(#(^7U.9A:!<96!9U~#!!:*&5~`@C29`*6@&6+G5%#!;7-@%~,)G@47U~_7&*9#C$%U^29A-^;7$G!-~2U9!9A!@G6%:+8%G#U7##2C!9$G*!~A%@|!=69A)6U7!G52A|@$%~8~9A>%U^7U~;=A#!%(+!G&|C!87G69U7#7|&!%G!|~5G23*C!^@U~?)#;87!G#U384A!C!!G^7|#^7G91=7C.*|G!(C!^7@!G|@C~#569G#5G!^7|!#9|5C5,?*C!(*#!C1,!$G!C6+!$8.@&!#9%C!C!!)6$!;87%G#&~<1G&!%~=@57|5$-@9U71U^6;_6!8_75~1!C!87G#5G9!~+57&!^(9)#C?~#17#U^7?~@#9+|;!^~|@%$~C!5$^C!^7#U@C!*(9!;!^~+!!9*!G#5G&|-~?%+?%@9"9+5`6C!!C6|9A5@&16U4A57;C1~=`*@%-~1U~@!!+1@C!~1&!#!=~0~;(U@#(*1U@)!1G@G!@1A|-7+8~=A#U~87U787&*!C6U~3C%5@)"~|$#!@&+5G@U@1A|#"~2G|##@#*!%C~*U78@&7C*!#A##|C6C-7!%G((%G&$#!(C!*87U~#|$~U91A#&!#^7U~A~<~C1)6C!@(8~7*#87*#A!@+##^~!G!@?|G#A#7G*C%%%C*U@C!@G52%97<U9!;A9`&+|@&G8%!G#|@G#7$U~89_9A&5,5%U.^~&2%=A#6%@8^^^^@1G87=A%(9#A%G^7U7@^6~8@*9!87#|!G1#_~<&2##7$U@&#C2U@)G&#5,!@-@)|##&79!!;|C!%U@~@|G#&#A#8~#A!G#C~7G*@G82#5%#=A:87!:1@&7C17:!97U~2A^C2@C!G*(;@$)#7C*C6$##U9|%(#&|&!C1A5@G@G^C~(45G8%8@%#!G6^6%#*8$#&86*U>&7&#A@!$G|^~C%!G*U7U7C!!#^@9"7C.*2@#A@3:#A98~#C*!8%;!G#C)-@!87#:@~!)2A-@(@*C5%"~7:86%5@#U@*&#7(C!:2C6!:!G#;^2A$U7=A917G8%@##(C!C!%(G*87#*U7(C6%!G@=74U~U2*87U78~8$G@G878.|@C*#891#*;C!1C!57U7@9#8@#U@#U^6@!;,1(G#6U@!~A!(~C!8%U~U~#U@^:#A@!G@&!@%!C*1G^7C6@#;A1%>U~5`9A)-~U~!G|!^7#,6)*30%*;@-@U7(%$-41G&G#9U~5G9U~@C%!|:@(^7U~#,1#@5=A9!%G1!G#@G8~U7@&#|>9A&2=A!%G!@;,5G(@U@)*#1~;;7#!(1<%#=^~U7G9`!9A!*|#A!97#!C!$~+#*=A#.?:3#A>:|##^@U~_~^C!|8(59U7@9!98$~+#|%-~U7(C1%+#`!;!~@C~@C*#6%U@$G^~#5G#!&!C!-~!%U4!=7(#A||@%&?9A~`1;U~#!%#;<?=A^7!#?@9A^78(9!8~#C5~A@"@G@&!!G!G^~U~!*!)!&G!-7@#9*9!C!1A#A~?$%)1~#7!@-@#!G*957!C5,!89|#U@8@;!^;57@9`?^@+|9U~#?+#|5,*!=%@1A&|^7#A#5C1|G>!8@-~_~|#8>95`!95^~_7(*=A"@5G!59,.@5C!8~+?-7|9<%%:#!G&57U~#595`!C1$$)#C)##@91#86U.6#"^.*:!G#A##C!|9&|:("7!%!=`^C5_7U7G!(G!1A-~`(U~A!(C!)!@%$)#C**U@U^C)6~^^(#A=@-7^@~+#A#+?979A9,69&"@9U@)#1G@%-~1`2_~@83_^~U.8%4*"~!(-7C*U~!(C!@=7C~&5~=%#A:!G?;U97%@##A&#@9&#7%@#=73U7|#7%?^@+-7-^7U@U75=~!@~^~U7#8(^@4|8~A@+!#C2*#!=7)87~8%!@G97U9U7%@9U7G"7G5G+G@8(9A~A@%C1U@G#|)*|(U~8@9_^~#?97##C!#A~375@C!8748@8987U~8@#U~!G#8~17@!%|#A;#U^C1#|@#@9A"~7|97^~`8@#^~>%=A$~U7C1_~A91G8%@~C6@G@(G@G^~!C~A@(C!|@G87#1A)8~*!C)#;8_6U~A%@~U~5^(&%?9A(^=7#,579*U~C!#7G!(|#79U^7@(%9A#8%@!C!~A9&5;^C6^~7*9G1A%!###=@82$|;C2U~!#7U~A:!9A!84!G#C?|$%#7?@91%#*|%(#^@~#|C59.#@G#2$(&74!>9A^~*|^@(1%=@C1`1A-9A%G!^(U~&5G+11G!#2#91!91)"4!|*C!#&#C1G(#A#5G&6@U7G@#@5^;5G1#|98^C*9A;!)|17"~&!!#9#C!G84#A#:!|#A@U~8~A"~8%!C!G5-^~17G^2%;#|#!#@U@)#!G#|^7U9|#A@G($;#!#A#_~#C!~A%G#U~A@=A#7#&8%@^:5_.?8_~U7#C?%&7G9A59A#U4^=_7U^;|=^7C!^@~#!G|(;U@#1U~9A%~!*1!###8%G!*3!1=@U7^~U7!@=@G#"7#C!G?*5=A~C!1#!C*|C5~9&1G?^(9)!C?%;A^=~#?#A|=`5C!>~`?%!!#78>4,!^3A37$!G@!%#9+6^(@86*84#8~U~C69*!&.!G9A;!@-^2#U@%#U.#>U@G!G&|^^@G1G((^@%G!$U@U@U^6*U4^(##U9`|@(#A@8^=`^6%!C!;7G95G27U~5@C!C5;1)59A#@4#;!%@<()5G#7G6#^~A(@4(9|()!!G9U@%G5`8389_@!#@)1)!;^($)|#`@~;*^7U~#A+#7G*+82`8$$G&5$#U~^6&#75%9G#A#@G9A#(C-7G8~2%U~;A&7)!#A36#!<@~C!%&#A~A(%4'|C!G#C!#@%(#C1@C!#=`.8~_7#A#@^((@|&7(#(%%U~*#838$@U7!9&|(@G@G96^7U~*U@!9A%C"7>"2A!:##_~!(@?=A#@U@G@*U46U97@~*!%#@%!-2*8(=`#6|G"~A(8@9U75`@U~9&|*U7@)57497+#;&6|@$U7#A)|-9#*@C!C%@%#&*#;9~!C!@C6;C*@;A#A(#:|)|C!(@(C64A~!~5G!C*@;8_9%?@~A5G6U4C!%83U7%G#_~7^~!C!&!!@$^~79A9*!~5G|@%>9<~U9U.#7G!?!C?86~06(9<!%~"~!=~!G?)#9A@G!:&!(G^~U7#(@$G#9#978(;!|&5;#C1)#!%#;^6)|C6%|&!)!-4~A(97U@^7*#87%#*#!>@^~!^~U@~(U7@G|@9~7G97"~A&7$U95~U~#@&G#*&#!;9G*9A@!%U@U96U9<~A1G#A=2~U7G!#!C6!9!(C*#^7#A3#U41A@=2A>G&#!9G&#C~!#U~6~8_~;!G*#A&7^9)$3A#=@-@)#A#@(&G1<C45)~#U7G#@G3G&|@9G#C~>~@C!G!;A#&G!!@4C1%@&!(#_.!G^~1G^689U2A^7**&)897G2~,$%#A(578%+|C5G!G87%%>C5^^7C!97@#7G6(5_7?=7~A*U9A)#*^6@#,+57G?$!%C~#A@U~!9A@!"@:&7:&|^6!@(U~@%9&G&!#C57~@1%#7~U7*#A>82G6!C*U>!(**#A#A#A|5(U2A~A^~!#A1G!G23A%!!|C)G!!:97=A~#7:#!:97)5G82A@G!(+##A#9A#:6#^~!*8~#!;A@|%U7&7%U^(U~U7^~!#A5C~#A5@!C69A:9A~!-~`89#*!%+||8@*87#9!!8798%9A4C57;@%->#8%@;A=7C.9|@87-4A5G82!#A=@C~7%%~82^C5%9G|16!84_@%@!9A36*#87;5~A#A@%#@+#@*#C6C57#10^C!@G#83A9!(G1~A9,!G#`2A!5G8%U~#89A5G!G5(^~A!9A=@%%)!~#*!@U7U@~A#<=A@!G^C!%=`17~7|C*#!#;;A3#C!#@C)#=^~U7&!|C!%<:@C!:#C1@G!)#@=A^7(#*C1C6;&63~U717C6%C+!#,5)##U^745C57~7~7G+#8$82@C++5G^@~_~U7#;C"@)%|#,!C!&G8_7&!97(###A"@%(C!C!5G!G8$G*8%U7G!C5%*|C%U~U~;!87#^797-@&G&7(9!%C6U@G^~19A57<U4-7~C!%C?|#0(#`|#A~A&7%#@C1:@!!C2C-7#U@U3!C"7^C6#7&87G!#9A|G#C6$!%G^:@9G!G^~#U^C!&#!G!C!#A97!%@G5@&2A|*6&7!G9G9,!%~A)!;!-78~7()6+"~U~8~@(@#82A;?!G#A#!G23U@98_4840_9<##A!%G9A#9U7@#=A$8_~9U@C*+*^C)6@!(:#*!)*U>9G5C!!%|G^7#`##^(G!8%G#6U~U@##U~C~8@C!!#869A~U~79U@U@~A%#9A(;=A#^7!G#1U7@5G&7)#U@C~97#87#@C1A&!;_~U7C2*9%U7G!#U9G(?(>%C?#`#U^C!!G6!%%#8%>%C5G#7#`1A:@!5)-6@5^(#A#A!^^;,%#;*##5(!G@=A#@U^(~&!-~C!G@<$C57-@G+?|&2(#1!#&#7)2#8~A;A%;A9|^6~A9U@#71G^^(@!(#C!G86@4#A#A|##!989|3A%U9A&7$U9!4G9~;1G!%#A!&-2A@%U~!@=A#0$C~+G#&?)!!%#=A3A=A^6@U9U7U@~`!#;A#&5@5G!=A(!@U7G6)!@#A#`87@~A>#|%@#!+#|#=A^7#_7@=(~!8479#`1A#A~C!#!>9G@!@G&|@~;84)*#+5G(8>%=@87%#U~#C*@!:!%9A+|#*<#;|C%9A#U@!&7@U><|G&*&#87U9G!#5G(#^9A~*#A#U>%##A^(C?=A~A~!#A)!|*<U><9A3A|G19A*##^7U~A(G1U~?"2A!@##8~!)%U7#|;,57#(*(@##A^~,6#^~#A|@1`^7@9#!;6%^()1#@G@G6:^C6)!;A~A%@56;&8_~!*C!;!:#7G#;&#A@%$|@&5@U47G8~<9!%9A9A=79G6|#&?^~|&G#U7^2A@-.!C6!~A%G!@95G2A~#,"~#A#;*?9%~!((=,686#8~#A|1G#;A@U>!@-7#907G#@9!@C!G#9A(%G@C!#|$|^~=A!37@^("^@%#`1C!G(#*C6|&2~8~!#'!+!@^9A4A9A9U~!^~U7%-@1)!8~9!G^^C!C!3+#^:@!G#!!@)*^^@#9)#8%#@C!##A$~@82!5G9!!%<#!G!$|!9#@:#^:#!%G#1%<+.#78(@|$@G!#&1G!;<#@*9#A%C%@G@%!!G*&5%#65(U~9,6|#A5%G#*&7#9A%|:#^7G@C!##!@8~C%3#^(|9#@9A:>*^7^74>C!$9A$!5(8@G##!%=A#2C!!~U9A%@#89&~7C*&~:*U9#;6*8%@;#`#C5~?#_7U7)8.><%C6U@G^(#C52#1_74#8_@:@#A#5@&#(87@~9,6!~C-~U7%$89|@C-73#=~`2)#&?5@98_78>$#;!G9&6%14,!97^C6;8%8@U>4^@$!#,!#U@!8@^C69A;6@G^@^C*U7#<@%57#*C!|9A%)2G!~@!C5G@U7#&#A!%%9?#A(G*(?(G&*689A:!~7#U~(C?()#2#U7@~A^C56%*!-7~U7U@^4|@U9!>~@9!>9U@G#8%@^6+2;7~?##8%@!9U~@!9U7~A@#A9!!$%^@U^C!#_412#7|&7G87U~|3U7@#5_@3)$$)"7%@#!:#@U~0~C+%#&%4G#U@#C!C!%$)#8~!97?9?@)!~1&!@~#879!G*;!9!@~|#8%!@9U7U7!@%1U9A%G|G#^69A9G9U~A%&756@9U@!9A=A#!C6~A=98~7#!G#:!<%*!C6#87G#A>=2_^^;A@%G&G!5G&8_4>U~C5%G8%@&!#7G!1G#2!~A9#A)G@9#*&!##A!%:#9A@#C19A;=@%@=A#9#8~@U@+!8~A5%|:&"7U9G?#0%#8((U4G1A@~U79!C.(9A#A&#!*&7-9_~U7#>#!)!G*#A#(U@#,!~#&!)#U9,%G#C5G87)G#8%^~,!8$"9"78~#A#7;7%87#C~C*!G6~8(>U~*86)#@||G@%C683`+8@C%@8~U73<)!87G##!9&7)#A#!$U~7G+!#A#>G9*!G#,6)8_2!$$|+!+|#9A>+#,68>%U~#!#9!1~7*(#&%!%"9#^789A*5G!%5%@C!%G#C"^7987C*9U~*#_~U~@G5G!#<<@#@89A>9A)1%U2G#C1G8752(|9A1&!|^;A@-9A##A-^@U~2(G!G#U@%!!%|#!9A^.&#C!:#"7@:*(?~U~#;&#!%@U@#^7#`!@%*"^C%#=_7@#A#_^@G^~C?)*U45,6(5%!=_79U^~7@C1A(%=@%G5`2#U~C17#*<U74A@C5%U~A(@4#7G!9`5C"@87U7@;?@'8%U~#8%#!$*5G2U2(@|9#87#!G@5%)54^7)G(@869`!9A%~#2!^(U754#U~A@*;^7!;#_^4,!C2%%#^9`>!!&!C!8~#5G+!#A;A@!G97G697;6C%5G#@9A^@;&18%U~!%G8%U~&7G!%=A5`6#3-7U~#+||@$~!G#86~?(9A&#!~U36()!G&87U~A->878~A$G9-2A>G8(|8_7G.8%U~#*U97(|9#6=,?^@%G!G6?($563A~`&6U~68%5=A$|)"~A#78@8$C~!<|$~C!#9+$@!&G5_~A%1A-@!-@G|~U~?@&!;0~,!G^6:17~7U@91$|$%109"~A@G!@G82,!5@U7@%#C)6@~8@U^7G####+#|8%?|=%#A1G*6U7U2U37%?&#!G5^7~*&.#,!8%C!!@G65@?#C5~#<%U~9A#!G6@1A32|(&!G&7)-~(94#*C!#9U7&5,2#C6$#C!|G2G##A9+28_~#A!G#(@|9<~@U7#A#7#&)2!!^(;#&7!56>87@|)#!3"7!#A%G|!@1~#^~+#_6~`*@9A~!@)#17%@-~*9!C4!C)#C*&%8@%&87#,5-^;A#@%8(C5%8~#A*#(;!@!@G^7<U4_^@||G#A!#!C%3U7%^2A#|'2#A^^6%418@=A@5-4?!(C2)!G^=~A~89-~C!<%U7@$@+8~7#;A&5_7G^@U4A@C+G@U~U~A@G95G|^7##7#C-@U@&#7G@1U78~A#U7|&8~C69,)$C6!%U~|#U@#@#C6|@!1~A~7!C6U978@G*&89!+?5%@#A-653=6874G!;;|#&52$~&6&7#A!#A1_^C+|-6~!%=_7|%G2(@%G*|5C!G#A#+*87(^6C$(#5G1&*1A*9,!-^C!-@G##87&|(9A$^(|39#@!@^7+5>C-~#?|3#,.1@%U9U@G1A@8(^@~,*+|95C197#|=~89A#C!!@#U^^4A97U~!^7%~5%U73#U9!9A57#_~#?1)89A;A$-^7@U7U7%~^~A1U~!C!C?%+$%3A-3!=A*87U7C)!^7#*|8.&##75(1-7#_9A1U4#?|9,2A('8~_~.#`8@%G?+!G#C$U7*@C1$!#U^^@G91=_~A98$~2@4U75C2A&|475G#57$!8%U~|12!!8^7G>:9!875`#:#_^3U@41&~C?$90~!%5G97!~!87@U@C!~5C6C5,*C?@!$G|5%^9U~#A++8@~8~A@G^~#;@)||#U4|&8(9!~,1C!82"7#2U~79A|@%#;!%;#@=%3U^^@G6C.#!:*6U98@;!G2A~7&!&6=^7C?%-9797@$&!*|%59U7!|C6C*#31~#7G1U7:9A9A%5G@&#?#=~7@~7%$U@G(;#*;A|+#U9!"789G@U@19,17G#8_~`#U^9!^686#_^;C?^7#&!#@%8@5-7|%~#A#7-@%C6&G^9A4C6^~6%*;0_78_6|9A%#A1A@~;:|!)8~78^7(&8%8^7~8~U~U78_7|9#!!%*?~7-^7U^C691%%%%!5(;6&"@~9~!G>9*U7U~#8$~17*|C59?(U@"~5973A^7U~#8~|979A!@%G!G!G!C5C1$C+!@#@9`(;5-~A9U2`&!^75~82,6##&75(=(U~57@~>~#+|;A-^7C2`5;9597(5~@%%@*;A@C!;A#;U9G#_9A@%@=%%+8%@|@9A#+1~U~#U@G#8_7@9A~7C6!=^79A~*;+5_@~A#87;>$-3#*C!8@#@%&7=A^9!=~:#?+!@~8^7#1&6@:#@~;57!4)#7@#&7(^@!#`##A@!30~#@~!!#C)!G8_@%^@%^78^9&~C4@:!G#!)!G&7U9_@*9!@C!#U@=~#@G28@G*=A^^7U7^C!*9A!3,61,!|G#|9A@G6+!9`#&!#A97%@U@G!%*!(#!@5-~#0(;7#@G(&1G*("~@G1#!@(869G#C57^~7!)#8$(%C2A@37$G1#@(G&6C65,2@9A9786%1~U~171U@C6!|9A%U9A&297G(%~U@?8$%&!C1(C.#A@C*@%#^~=@&6("~#A*98~#A!*;C!%%9U@5G#@'57C~9|;1G9A95G^>%#6#A*^(!@C+#@;|)4!(U@=^~8~A95~#@~#;@|C6!9A5)!#C6U~=A!~57U~!8~`|>$#8^C!#A$920%*979757!G#C!8~C28(%^@C5=9A@G(G#@=~2=(%#U~&792#@()56@C)*86(=`^971~#(5(G#16#A"95@:&8%C.8%~;7G#C68%!~8%U>~@%C+.5G@%@!##A^((87|%)#@G6U@%)+#^7&*;C!^2#U@%G##!=~A(&2A%G8%1#U~64C"@&|#U983U@-@G@9U@U~#!G&+*@##A=A#U3#@(G2$=@(;^9#9A5-@#_~2G>C59&G#7~#&5G5C6U~>@^~5-7@C6~71!#79,6U@|C!@%(>5G#U^~U7;#A#*U7!~7*&7(>G?#_95G(9#7|%^@8(~A~`|%<!17$U@!@U@9A%#8%?~#A@U^^~@87#=@G*<@+2`68%9G9&7#A~*97$56#7U^^@&%U^97$=~.!#`@G!"2U~9_~!@5~C!~1A!G^~=%*9A!-7U~#A(|#C5)#!#A9`*;!G*U^(4;*+*U~_9#;C65%#7%C%^;`9`#^C6~`&6|@|><C$=_~A5G?#A$&8@(8~7;U7C5$G(~#6&7~A#C!^98@%1G+))!;(C%!9%!(G9U@^35C~_~=A*8~:*@C+*;1U@%))892U@U73&2A%%U~(C!G@^^974#8@C5G5G(C*;**5-7@G?^>91G^:*;^~98$G3C1^C!&?#C5`&!C+*@%G!<C5-7$U7U7#A~C5~C5G^~6#9G892A3A|C?#A#97C!1C5G^~@!^7*|C%C!*!!9|(!G#U7C+8(*U@|=@~#_~@((-9!5;7@#,!9A%8~U~|!;2_47U^~A-2%;#*!|>G|=@=@%C!|9A)#!^(^(8%G!@%@^~#8$@#|9+8@&!(U2*8%#`9#7$@#U968>(&%C~8@U9~`*87U9A-7U~797?#A#79%C%C%C!C!)G#95-7G@()#A#`!C$=A#!^@+G5C~7%%@~!:87!G87!)G!C+1&*C5C-~!+*C!G|@C!G9_9|;C)+%*##:!;;(!*87:#`&*U29+1!:?^^:#82A&#7++!%G89#A&8^~U^6C$^6!|!|G1&#5~7C571`9_~@%897C~!C!|9G8$%)82`^98$(U~79!-7!~59!89|@U~A5G&+!(5G9!#97@~7!~1#!"787G8719U^~;8_~9A-7C?)*1G#C*;;?@$<8~_@9~U~7*C!&G(U~C*&*!~=%#U~^@)!=@*C+5@%;5))G!C)G89A#U~U@8(U9`6^7@+8^(:#9A^9_~@C!+#A9A%9)+!G.#7^C-7&~A)##_9+-~A@&+G!*^~A@9A&!~,)##A@&7~A9#9U.6U@;*C!@U@C$C)5=A|C684A)+G@)G#!G@~#A^@~1)#@!@G&)!@~0~(C!<86>%909`!G@G#A(!*C5)*!@-7G#A(@%#5@U^:8%C5@~|C!!G@%%!|^7||#A~,1.59A5~7&8%|@U@<9U@U782A5_^7-@^7;A$<!8^(|%#7%G(97U~A%8%86C$@#2|+1=~@;_7@^C)!C*#A)5_@C!97%G##|%~!(@G!C12$9*^=^~7@!C%4(8@9A5@U9&!)#_7C65G@;,*C5`@^(5)1)*U9#,~C-2@:&"@G|:#9A%U@G5@9<;8@U@%(%~7G8($C?^^971&|**C~(!G#5_7@C5)8>^'6%@$#0$C5@878%C+!5G#C1!G95;C!89*17|#=A|&1~8^@=$;(%U@U7#6C*U@:9<C$@#65C*1=A~7U@U@(;!)#@5@97$#!G?@-@#!^(@&79A!#!G8%#A3G#U9!8@C+!8^6U~!!|%G!~A)!G2U@G@9578$*#C-~A#A~^~8^6U@30@G!@&%!&~U7|!@G59#?91A(87*9A~79<84!G&*!G#:*+G+!#7%C1!%G"@#A:+G#*1A%5@U^6C$C6^2#&#_7U~A3C2U@)G6#@3:@|:5~U~A3U@%8(^~@-79A$U~A$:@-4))%&2(:&~3(~?37U7!;:&8~8@9G^^@^(@U~(~7%98683&%~A(~:89787@97!G@-9A%#A968~C!C!9$%)!9A%C$+-~U~#,~U2#6%U^@-97%U~!5C!C!9!~7^49A$G^~A=3"~#^7C6%C~@U@"4*(;A4`98$!@92%U>8~@3G(U9#^7(#;(&G#C!(=9&7~7(@*92~C+!:@$4`@%~C~@G&7G9&8^:89U@U@:!G&G(@G8(G68(^9A~@G@G!4$=^9#C!$U~^~(U~C~#A#;^C*C5)#;=%@%8$9A)8%%)2#U^~<~97(((~96;U@^7G6&#;;A~=^7$G9&~C2A:!;9A^.@!(#U7@()5C~@%C-~U9A$C637~614%9A~7^7U@%(~7;A|C6@8~9)6*@(5G39A))8@)G++~7#&)G@8~@U~7->9+47C-~8%9!>~#9A&68~A#,6%U965C6%&7-@1)#7U7G@!8%:@!C2@83A97@%G9U2A~,2A$$~;A#6^(G9|9G@%%@$G6@)6;#A^C+89#;@%5~A#A5^96(*((U9A#`@G#;A^(^@~9<^@#@%9A@(~@%U4C!!<:1C)19G5,%!!!G&!^C*#@$#78^C-7C!@!G@(G!%#!G87C57U^>!G(&57U@G##U7@|4A~,*6%G9A9A@1@9%~9,)~`!C%&%G#!@G#7(#C!4A%)#9!"~7%G3U7##U2871`!G#C"3@##A17!)+|~A$#,22222222A
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LZvLkrO41qavRRaiONjOBBuEjA8iGDDOAbMO7B50RA96tqeEbn3387r@qqivqjKdIK3De1hS/uf//e///N//85///vfn7@d/8ffPz@/PNPwdfsz698/P3C5/r59u@nv@xPh3/1n7v/NPv/wdf6b57/MzLX@3n3n5G39m@7f/DNPf42ce/uqfYf57/0zr3@lnWf/Kn2X@K35m/1f9DMtf/rPOf9vPvP65n2X6y34W/2d/1uUv/szTn/lZp7/0syx/4Wee/4afdf3zP9P01/wMw1/74/3f5SfMf9eftPx1P8P61//46ee3Ty8ThsuUVj/3wQc/d7Nbt7kyLrfDtvVzNndtbu2axjVucxqjfXxs3OItLgc/@NVvfh/zZXAxTXF2J7/dcpPXNqbxcUzdfAqLreIS3BrXuDxz8/3a1dopLD2vdWua3BKq9bKmrpjd0j75vt/i0i3BNlNMdeludruZ@ZTmjg9v4ZQm/s6Hd3Qp3nIf86HnOXGu1vT4mGyp2indmiXk/pHF5WKsHWLe3@o02W3OxhhYTFqjHd5pcMuWzBIzvpHiEBczp3wxp2QnFx/Jrt@lRbteb70J0yk9WHiR6ro@@WxmA/f02dKawmSWfU43Nrr1p9i5x5RmN7tySHF8h9161xRLuyUftz7yQt6wXxbLTu3NTuXg5zRdl2iIcmls7lZfzDVxv9h3ms0lZ6E2ss9Q88MEJN3LIdo4d6eQFVs6vkjB5t11scaMI1H30X6i7atHMnFO/lbb1vFkX0UXQ7P0Qz@k@dx3/N9QrNeMrfbNYroL3whvn3s3m6EI/lq1S8sCifDcva8mq6mN/BA@1XyKobfeFvxpQ1ds7MUv1r4jibD9gyBHN19n1yzDORyrOWtORGPKOrf1WbLhaJSy/TFd5taO1dC@qjWw6DUWQ8wWk6bAHsySVyEzrMn6dUtz1YZJ4b@uZCrOpgqURRpJ8vaY7JAqPlmwjGCG6xCmm51NuWw@mlStnjzFZKshTVkaQkYVeTsVoa56s4WWUjyrnrzhE/bY9Q/e6Vy@hGlvUsyb3D7CxMNndtKPtk9d@n2fY93PfTVkayBhq2/O@9ymdtlazybX5A0P83Hpee44nUL@srFb6AeXxu1mKzO73DfbZSH3VT9uc1tbioLiz1IoD74wsyH6vnsuZiB@bouDY1eW3T5zO3UUyOaL3CxskFI0cY@UJLuMNOZcq9g2GjXmHeF/2Xba5v5yCoMb0iNz2dL5xEqNW7rH5Nychiu76bv3VgRr54oiynnesa/WqC/0qR@82pa2crHufFnd743Kg6iPPPwQ94Ef@Gz94xyG7EUxxO4EZvDe61SZuJzJVr@GiZf3GyumcsK6tcvln37P691dP318XAgA7/DEyS9VXtE9dnoV5CIrAjGhxks7ZMsWftNAlYdPR4D8fKUMqu3W5717Lu1iRnup6HlvaCUBXQHmPVlKmpONYF6f9rnh0XaKo53AD1ukvWB71h/i3GQPR6J/3Xo2lMPEt7cxGDYxABq8Njv19lODVrZSwVuQcm2P3VKEj8mtp7xjmLYrOXs5C4J8DuQrsv7H1OkL7OrT0YyPp7Gmqju6XZGxgJz1GX0yVfo32QEop9xvhbE8w4yez@zBpzsN4Dv1U23H7UHSPJ8u@JEh7U77ooXY5jik3BfkNy56eEEBFjPrqPuiGlyi2XO/O1WalvyhfAQB7NebpWHhe9c@pnEqQJg4tJMl@ezYkwDwdm2Dp84q@gm49/YVhh4AEFJDAOnD/67@30K1YbIF0cu1tD2aki/yyTA9@hNNTRnbxpfwSZFXgOWYA3RU4KWnFkgWHRkHwHHwpIhUt42HWuKcLTV4Qqx3mEGoTklSjhdWS40SPqDRmZF2mHubE/3S5p1b2/dGKx37ueqKkh8B0Xhuu2iFc@vyEiYYwl01OHgS0L392J/6oObKIoRVOPv2S5v3ZUU1ZstegIR8ut/4ibBSgnO1zy8DQEOYqWA7ym9NGOj3nVxQGqDB3D3OvbMbEGXM6UpwqqFwV2IxjqCkoUuIs8gG0Bv7L6z1JUXRLpbYu2I/AG@A6XWN167nR@JoHPGfe0fGH@3HrvoouFJDZbkZ3tv2Lehi6esh@bF7UEelW3h29bQ0Xx/nkl63wX41QL@dxXPwNDEtT/3BX83QGi1yhUmhUxblmmOjij@1xWjKU3xQss@Hl67oba8dqwAelIJd/RPG7qnerLTqJSCNj23zmU@UdFjHkoCcyY57LBEc7Cnf57oetjaqymMzVX14b1D/BpybOxW/gvsb1Z2byDp5ZtY9wPBk3624cSd4J8@HAmEPUxCywlqUTOgcuaG4Znqwc0ATXXIEUJJ9FQgDV5C/QOrirQBpqU@bE7544GUslRfTN116JwprsvvW0hJAgR@e1tMerBVIB4a@QEPN3SxNNzcOyaHFFMgE@my7smZR4ALbr09SDtOYC6Sj4un8XBu@fo0SCOMOM05jpOniJiADwgfBOYsMBJTM0CA7RVpcQRnQcvNzg44gJ/sSzAhdsF@I1n52AeBO7gv@W70AIvuXqyt6YMlpBQQL9SPC1nYpt8vgr9aQud2auF6f1C@AVXRUfhIzmFCxxzXdi9LMrYGeTIFKPEl97LxMW/yukwVY//AwIjvvjpUVtH9QQqD1Hj7iVJJ2jwf/2M49LGOqaIAxO78ex/5EkDMDLpBTFBhBBtPObVz2WBTh3YbP/ngDrxRnxY9Cw4O7rGScfYAUrNYV9d49CVLwg8srEySFp0Pob0VZE@fGgx2IyLc3ed8puVPXh8/gqTn9fLCPwqH0znts1osFxlYFk2VT5GoL2sg8L3mjyECK1R7vwVSQMYBW2AL0o69u5h6QmPyoMbcKqv7EmcVXPdK1BvstgH@CCo/lEq@UAhKtCnbOaBgE0WkbAWJ0a/stbW3T3WqJRgrOtlQYshhB5eJuHj3dBRrTyS3VkQH96NcnD@KxI0mk1FGZdBrFz/Z4gt9zasvsqVvaSwWKk6tXaceBh9j1MlwnitigsnZKbAkN/X4G2kwhwEfB0XXJErTFEkk@ZWzYabLji2cVlTVzc4R3yWJtsuEcc77vRE2m7DMzfpE@T/dmYRXpETu/d9lJlN4AKuO7B8ogwMZ8F8wrgklAfm4QMCVVksBQy@5eRDzU@2g2sNFlZKeDwlmPVYFViAp9qzaqXD0m30@JFnghkQ@h7j49C5r7HQ5ACtKEU@dHlMPjg6Y@JbgjGlM3PCo17MA80m8aYVlbVM0aS9MsVDowsJ88cPtQhchBDSSSxyL1Z9fF8pD2jIbK669E5NP2gJbcrYUEVfVoPNyMx6NRY3af@/nkyU2BYMn5QSJeCSnsntERYA4r@dJrugM2JVtAXCcPVfEPdYLUlAEy8SUmAgmr2aEBK0UEVGtd8HdKapzCB2EWZfWIzQ6h@Iz1hzdM0h3h0fOW8hbbY2EbrCNmANkPIjr0CFqRNcj6pCFWALS3O1iHHrvnrdWTYm7nliAtue2OJp5iyY5zj84ad6nfmCLrk2JAS8NBdpYmhIJb2wnkblTirVFcGn8zgQ1L5bZsYqmKMYJSRGzuMzAs7K6wOQU9NySSnMA8xbVjY4CWNfA2LIyat9jKan3mnrdGqnPHe7h/NbanEMCtcFCZt5HvXzBxgaWRlsGNWh/Up33eYjIlIB6LWMEqB5wYLq4TwleoQ9J1awHuGz8yAvbZSsgCSIEksPYrzxxsw4MqOcKeBcSHrM/aVt/iSQA@YfBCH6T6EBpbjbMBBDtFPIDEVv5VrnM84kFtv2KFJlN8wUkgxfexIZNcKaTpEFEN6Zr7iHpqHBTdfQCMU5I029UtR6TO5ddVI3liVS47XWnNRV6H3pM@cWa/RQEbLqrB7TxEtEvDJlkrsE669yeVg6AUrsRReplyR0I1aRw9ddzcyasoYEFHg2gVnEFiwQqTpdpWVNr5dQNunzdKRYD0TjTzPhRd0MYR@frcTmcqcg2C60N/szhNCqhSaAOVaCULqQWgkzK7IvELRCnwkL/ClD7NKEBG1N9fj2nDQrwk5j1aWaZOA4l4iIobLbRIm5kKPasJAv47VLIp9OCUXpkr8RhepU2N4Vm9Af/MEHbCj6sz29ix6s9ri/UuFnixdsjQPBwgkO9Sarabm315YgJPbHbH/YWO2HQbZFAQkAO20nTheI6YiCHVrxP8eXfuxhvzTsno9ANYGvphLoEUqgU1ce7tYTtXqkEghRiGfL8VB2DFPD4brp9KAssXIxfwKVZVD@qTWtFzKrBi3RCKaduI3SOe/BaJ/GTrl4g0HPuQHzR0KS0QKKT8tO8Uh8ubgJ0Hd61wM8XJS1vowRT4nCBAfBesuLxGlJW6YcpZcC75bx8eCtdQReE6@ROVRiV2mnVIIXs7FFu84kKldUEWKObhS6Qc6CV7sgYJH/5AVELueAIyilfB8QDV4FuJTAXeIuKSVFB2X7@dLr6LIpnrgHgUzKq7aAtQqYHnHDU60mtzA0Ky2Il2x6Ft6cPntvQEHjNZ0AaRiArS1Iw2W2KxfA3LLM9D@NXPaMVySBCDWPbda0wmU99tRe6ozGLDix47HyqJDKv0EA48tI@Fw1/xaEqPt@TdiNXFj1QBE@eQMfaBe8v2EbxN/CRPvqm/hqtQ67VnznqKvAEDBZSkEpLpwpnOtW1W5Gh@OndL1b7FonEPHPKHusDRwOzELCecTYNearEaJjTl4Wp2aB7wRnsWquIlxxqi9wAGqh4e2MOAMUDKmnJv/CHRTngOsHuQDboZwkp/k82DEsjXO1wzILm1bpT8tIIOK16iEII@jf0drRjy60m@wwopdilUcN0BeN37/Bo0EGDTLv86O@K2XrcH5b6N@wMINNo9oFfg6W2jKZ@jwRsFEWllqotpHuxEFUfVEqCD16pfVafxn2kAK6xfl0LeLC@JEcO7xml7UFOgzONDnz7T5@XYLz7hejTbZbr4DCQGc0Ldb3iOviIKmqfMPbokP5tFgYqnrQU5nF3P9knJSq/BuQshpvRZXKaJK7BfsaVCtPdBEMtrbvR0ryiObBo9J1tBUc/d2JQKQbxafGNEtgON6D8rNxWvRdgR8rycly7dZ7jA/ZHIl01pxq3IIOxPTGP1Bf2plpKoh/YjR5x3GdHfenq3c0EgQw9OsNtJMryFhEZMYkm68PgIfULn8u@Iwl3/2eUGKB8cBwXEQu3jc0bOCw/jVhRxzyWiNbeA/i54cpIBgMmkLKHXcgAoKtzNB/88tBOmhKrAi4DoKpwlEqIejIm0m@M95gS3Fo@P7fdF5m4QUHQfKpDHQsOx7Pw1@NqOeY98lqMr91OwlaLoSEle2THQzibO/ThXcYQBCnvbS/ZS0OH9dUoGqtS4guYO7oUv6hYUJRsfQDaq9Z28EAFqMjGjfcHRSj8DMz3DHWlH3un6FxU19Om3L8IdbQyQgoEL0hxHuZhbDmp/8bDQKC1g6QZc@Q4oEMvyS2xbz7J6hx4qzenKdkHHuH0FIhBgzRMfhipGgRVsnfcHlFegSUlZtoZOAgJZaFEzZgwwG0JC0/5ASO9pwm5Oj1Y0jiJG6AQQvrJiswvN1tCS7fRE9ZnAHzOAtCZE4juNGgNp2hXK7DKBWUhCZbzIl@Y@X7sS2eIlJy4UfgwShE8NRhakqoV/TbzC@RBzYd9nUTOaph/Ciiz0VZWXQ/BLm46g3YRlHVy9y1gCvM7hZDc1PxWh@i/gv9fDp6nCVpdWIyl7xF4sr@zrQgVNMvDmoMOIG23Yo7E1Cgw5hgWR4FMETj1BYEvPoV16Db6fOJ9KZhIk6AoWlkBVegDsxGQB1djZko3cNFdAOsDi/CdNObTKbYFynzRKu6lDvwNrth53DGvu8XKFRtHfB3ZaZAcf4PtusBxS5zMEuYl63wdNDyw6e/BhgDmuLHeEpJ@ikHGSkQt7HPwJt8ObjQge7e0wjS3SgHbeG/zX9R2dmuzSq3BGdBFxoZlqG/HzmHYI7XeTpaBHEYPF0kBORxl9OlLimzIawOBF8yUQh2c9Iq7aYNsNLU39Tfb@kErlMe7xaTzcSikZO47UkhACrvwqxtzIM9xvUUMWMGMxpWYeGj1Wc0NP5v1Fc3o0rpvRB0dMvfzhtZu/o3C/1HbIBtxDjQuDA740Mc6HWMLwR3XlguPMqRCQ1aK7/h2kfgsIn81mKHeCA/h/FfYoJ7D5gIGnJDzi0WH4xPkNW8ZgXU@ajTro1/5qACPwI4tsqblhKucWqATt14sBxOBz6/NBHRUmXBG2BhG93egCFbr0h6GhNFfClKDi8HExx@pXOoFYwkLcXZqAbVQqXrAo@/qQxK@YFEt1ja@vElQZrjEM7@tw/X2HOzs1GkFb6Ws8V0abwgZzVVeSf9EUOswoqeywQGyoIWyE/SDOkY4aRfTfUzc6fEY3yUINVCQv9pqTkV8obyo0gNg0Vmh4C1LBl3LnCQmm0TKeLTfjd47fVuEbZ6htKV7Fk@jxMm0eD2eco4D5mjjMIlAIY1eeehRH8Z2Ib9t4BP0qa7tCnkpUsBUojxOJWOI9oxROcalfe94WtpF88WULD0/jBIUHupwCZjseYIGmwRnplT5evw1tATS0PW28hn@B0lyXkEaaG8Qx@Ykedpp38eLfbE415vYFvcrLXiZqFYUUvlX/ocBBtE7a/jEV6oWlR3vzms8AZ01PPA6eArtgVeP27eOjSLSkD9q4lRIBxoMOF4WVaRyu@CwquxhQpFE4v8q5RlwoCFDvtrpbbLd0JMyZ@7g@7/uSg/BIXooMBVdoTp0EX@vTURhbMUOnaRLelOi9Oz8CGlCeVDhB/o4gaPo1vUTBVMGALyZ/dsf7wU9VIYW/paPQTMcCzWeTfTVj77aixERC5/2N2qduJ6nhjj6mAg3acqTPIYNRTt1leyRa61Xa4h60I6DEh6XfCfGW9lwzMax2PJ1FSNKGJkoIAbLHgyZ3Y/UKCL2ieBz7of9OHHZ4DHQFtLE3NvyKeoIR36hmnc4h7Z7tW8LQXjy65IAII/x8QKDTU0U6o7L/mNpEQndlUbg8Eat3p4iGGlKgezfhyKW2dLPRuBpHrGPVUFLNVi@xk86pW6MhFxinNs92E6zOhG86w7ONu9dogwFllGm0ivY04x0c1hwGfYIFo0OqvHO2h3cS/gy86ZwonK1Nbr9piPd9mYlDmt2FDt6D/MztWekk8frEhIcpMx3iaOFjmvu0NF7SyQYYEvKEncvTDc60IwoWLqE5kcIvKzdZDufn/X8wkMbpWtu8PSr3HW8qbODKFipu1mbSLAfvMtopAoMX@0iftiSXnbAJ2ZyhV5eQ965BQAfB46hZzvq8bjED3Y2qeNDhI8IZu7XpnJXKu0dH5VXyu5Mr28UkOFJTN69BEwgSEOnFUgEuFH@vs2STgOFErRcl/mZV@0GCvatA0qR23a47jYuopzqeQVZSZqOv29Gz9a8t04CEP7wOEGBCk7lN/tnY97VpNWn131H/fhHKdu94KbHrB7leqhyt8ZvmGo2po37g5zshwoZTXMG/wiuW3@kjvgVCJ80jiitqVoDxFaBgVFyjLC0wx0ZEgiY2Ew6o6@XRxbuTlFqaHgFykKu6mbvTiNJqujo9H@0b9KTTFnQWCA1BPHX662Ro868ZpVva7/H9VC40cZWbL3ncJEthZPIAuQv7AgsH@2vKnxLcb/lBCPOyv8B3UazXRVdAVnYynzHoGgEYqvQUvoz8tGhWyUSrKesRqYCIhQ6O1DKJHHyp8G86xMkO4eDVyNaP3sEkc5oreCINBWuvhh6FsO@0xtwPl08NPbmoQdXlXn5nysC5mIjIZKv0gazlc/nOiY99Obxbk2V7bcDOMD1rvga0anKEsmrw3gX5Mu4QaCzKSOcQrnN0mBZ6QBgMdEuQgXnreO973HC/44/5MGa7bJxO7mYNVLuWVpzI8K4UYLutjpApixaSVUU4ES/LnbYzgpqSOfh4o4al0wFIo6NG6e8PhVAdthnGgTHklDcJkvkFgV@7I7LXGb4TVt1ZgXYLqELGrxV/N/TNffXXKZL274nQVWkPGNqDTjl9HF/xn39FnSNm7LhdWxApiMXh186V3XUjQTK43wGfS5QMqtV3169Vr0ZUwMiqaOq5dToY/TzNd1Q3aGqnFIySg0FnFH7sZ9cJlKctjnmjV@s0jH/RT8Kn7tPby0nmFNUbs@/Qpk@6TkBQ0nrpcbfUsnjq9By8bogs4SRzMvx7TnT@bgdA8wLD/nF8fX320r@KrOsvU/rkCJx@cJj/bC8POr4f4gC5m/uuwwYMfQadLt2bfmumUzQIjJ28vOia8ZcyxaLcpGtRXU22Z675DTxGpwZI76OB1TysIq2FgEKwUpfWQvyDe@2aljVL1dPj7Xrx7iUJ2G0@VfmZ3hicDm2XvosvwbC9O40zNO6OzXRpd10focJPqQhXYaJEXt4dW6lLjQR1ygxc1a1OeTWAVzLvKX7PMwHMsjVkb7QozK4nfnHHXl4OXke6y25ik@D12r779NEZPcqntA2gdkoakl4154IwNILXlZxjd6K88eJDQYEN3zsQGFcpmE1ymVrddV4hT6nTPAef2/2fFgWx9e7aDGBL7E7XF26zJa/bA2kyBGk7Nu5jFnXgDaPnmDsIYVUl1zqBVOlpLKKBK/uaT1FnE9Bho2E7cgeAHjSKOZaZDlwBasEwqNbvkV6fktdhDkY7wrFDMPWLTqdH@@7y6Ad/hYxHlEjXZinvdYAsy/fe5no/9ZQsLbfrUgGlVe3d/BXiNRat0GW8grpv8qqZKiT8Cc44iX0Hn@@UcQZJX2Bp9IWvu6cObF/7xR7PDUpTVASUaiyajlW9hw4URnw9iMpkVRoo5w1V4iVKvEu0NVT7PUyEJMn5q8Ez03HZCV32PThO2DQEHQ05v1yduct0uiBRv@cSsy512GofACHru6JBNb3BrfXKosKxnYp/dCR7RsOy01etGU@GP9Z9G6OlRJ0iakw6ZKmNV2Bhbqd8v3qavPPZ9@hibyi6gTZ43nSm1H3sDbzAs1ybHCDLwi8BRSh5gxz2umKh64eY0WM1v75HOp3bwndcBeJrvigEtGMsd5J6JdE4tXRExA3twdtWTkXH6ZqPjThKKk8L7ecz1EznBc3xpSOxhnmvAeLLnXStMma5qXangwmjE7vKXnQYgBz2N8lTFkmRvVA2KAqkDsmilapx2mulAOYK38PAcGzoeTpQPieYTer0vY3zi1jnGpENFD318@W5k8gsXyQ2NQBGpIy/yKW3DjCFFRDreNtNSSMMuj6GZgItNGik0qlCtLdx1St9p@sST43jLyTf2OcHpBkI@gzfG2eY5dR4TTrDCyY@pC74y/QdBA5pD99Ld0JKWVLqLsNzazr@KcbuJBPVfnKqpUtgXK9Tv654FLrrENNTaD1CcNi9TzcGHlx0KToHPUy6BoNYRy@otKQnnKuRIDv4Yuvm35MthcsLcHQ9gpTItYw1sopeHvz4zE4XwZ3uUqKBMFDBPNLNUpEUBGFt8h5pTag6b66lblXi37do5Gthn8tv4ptYWQpel0jQcg6O3xDA8zXqREUSJUfUvHXwKVG96l5pXFoBBO/TweimW4wYh2PfHIFau2t619fwqdI66fhDI15EWIEkJ2j2txh10apA3FfFAcnQWB3s6oQd4wplG12NKxxNEy8@49sREdvPPZCuWxd@QC4TocY3tEX/lcByqi1sWjhs@mvInI5IC4qbSFdUPeYm5n0hi1SF7zGsThqRyWsU8/7TeWz6jsXl@d2y4Qt7PrlhWefaxnEvr4bqeGxqtNApbrTarpng1JVEEPbEPSUdVEHxnx1hP0gXT1lof12lRur8dxgMALdDQazn7qFQFbrTktpHISeb@9Cy27LT7SWUXfH4bMHTb0XH5xrWdAhdvFHvM5SeRq8JCvI4ASlP3Vitz7QjQv1ra7Ehu0McLngVV2LMfK5d/zt8ly586K6Rbo4OrtHw8ooCyoGPMABEJ91x0W1jncDVlSyuzv0vykabPWIxbgHF2J0iENsuTzoIe@oRst3SKSCavtLSpCj5BmmNIVqJGf1UPAn6Kv846qoYyILOpDafqOd30PVDvISuihZw0md3d9PonN1QSep/JMN3dLlt2ElvHxTjPdbth0gE3Zy29EnwCBtdut1i7gAcnz3SmcqnFA@AISKcYky67jBp8PRwKuKvxJqKnTosdQITPpVmuetWXMeqrtb0xhFSh8563Og2fihyXcb8aJi@P@9zJtjv2MWU5cP3ssIIn3TZUiQLYSbR1QbUumapy9KMxexMcKbQycR26WZoRSSE96TuqrFR3qCuVieEF2XKycGhQTd2hOekiBDcxVyNVaVQL6/tGZplu6FAE/SzXOZGEzXpJoCKZwrM7jOfzcSDGrB0uvwKxtqw8CbNPeaXprNeJ/H6TgTgNA2k0Y0JeyGp7ud6KCrS@aAT3ikWxSmYbvSyMqRISLybsX1fde15OumsqzL7c@HzD13N3DWORnRthQ6jqNhNSBxBD9gsp9dafLf9fC/K6Xb38Cxy3e7FoCLCNMqZlCzaSmv1wenCuvwktimwu4Um0pTJkBKU4hZralKjXwBP9y1wI3yUgCBJwPVTMjVIqrs@iPI3SDCXtass9nEcC91KudlPXq1tqBtze23bTbNGtFVdS6njFfOBcpbO2QAkcLDJbQdud775UGuwG/GU3NiJcubKoaWxATltgbIDOYLO03XrFFdam0IzEl2NBA0T@KhfWGDNjSzNqNkl25fdwaySfAxLdkeTxKCJZKUZL09Gk1ZGJ9Fr2rDWj1jNdRfd2JXaeblIPWmqORRr@PQoo3rYCtncTSueTW1F76FE4JwtOH/yue4H0qE11BfzejEVyY26j5mOpThFJQ4orGc6fWQd0i3ZXOIqwMrhOpXoVDJEAdNnyLmmtN/JXglj/aqy70P/dOEXV7Xopi@hpxUrDa70fwA5PmK7AX9dTLumpfApdtLvGjsfm3MHICFhBkco4/3fO4zt1L03JMXmUYB3RFexq4F1Z07TA7QDaYu23evmod948N/fY0DoTCVcq7MUgeWuqZp@x6Jps1BtD1lLBPxVR2wTqwry72@YGgAeEWndJ25FVzalxkjHNJ9acPuAaVKE3aq5driPg67SF98LukWGFhLa53tVzUlthsCnw8vhuf3Tu5hp2tqBeLoYbzqZaoq1A9GHUDVeI9Q9b2D@@MjGQudY3va6DXULd22w7@aqeUyyaGvUBVcbWYPPSMfre7VjK0hgkDGBEOx0WSTgwJiamIHnxqDujYbvGGKRQ@eHrMJm6MAEQa0PxcuvLF/uTK4bkLqGFewrYMEHX0nJhLsO63MNH25VLScMlDY00QGjcasXi0NwSrJ@f6eHqnIN3ZJ@zUJXrHobL7e433R0N0FSmCwA6sSqM76Q3eLpWpYub4tbni5Fel00NRohTN2HWCAD9giEggRh6IdL7mDAdKM50dho7UVTCbYe9AsmuttKq36PX7Nad4jI49rq@s3G5/T7P6b7fgr62q4sAbCcHhdExvY9ntF06HCtinG6fmh2E0MLTQ8pXmhPzVMKOxa5REHxgLaSL9BZbSLet5hdP9El3XfX@T7owiKVN2QZzY2nLpaevRNSDZfNNXtsunVAFLak3v/OgrdZ7WPHhyNQWdBvwriyFfPeE2q0KFLo9ctRfulzHUUlRGa2SP@1E8inOYwOBzCdSJJZ@uKkKSmJufjUN1enjOr@iiOio3o8DimUfRXBrwvvKwdyVtdJJnuJGpchyZ@hvnqeBFsbRDLw0cudHolroEZ7tKymylY3dyJm6UaftVFHbx720jFowoRlWUJB9xvcCaZKVuvOd9mjKDCkQPIY3fcor9tCX1QFEZ9E//otDznJcN@km3V7mY3p@Nrcb81cNmHpjs4ALQh7QIC2QxMDfvrFB113MbpoNwja1@1pkLGd7vBbRWm/srSq10ETz21icAmvnT76LRkwRCeIXmct1wlZhjeiDJeLLrmuLdj@kT48XCS0Gtip3iloe2z/56/pv//9/w)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 7486 bytes

```
•тûιX>Þ*ι+»¹œΛaá3ðwkç.qn₅‰HYNgO m$ǝ‰š¹¦øýŸ‹ÁKÝ9ʒgāBVδ)EΔü§ý7Q@3)Züf†Bª*Ωā8∊á-<ãäε¬JåS©ÌтíH´λÁвáλ%ò¬õ+Pð²ǝÜεHC°₁+íP)Î‚©≠àlíδĀ²ƶèKä¹vôµǝÏÕĀ₃TùÈ]«-Ô™εˆðʒì—zÆO¼‰ÙÙœ2gǝL§´āǝ¯xïd>Å^ºÁ%Ü|M₆}×i“ε*Ð³:tнθ§òΓθIεïdƶ₂&ñd®ηôΔÀxåZS–€wÇ
b»fÒ∞
xFØØÎuŠh₃м£[üï/θú‹*,©ÔÐ`êζlΣº¤¹Áǝ¸нòô^X¬ˆa8ƒ(WÖx°ˆËÛHвù{±š®÷ÈÑþþW‚±²PÚ₄ßŠNUNdZÜλ¸ù<ûí≠ø
Ÿ½ÊÑ¨Yā¦’ÀMðŽj∍Õ;βpJŽΔ¢Ï^Hd‰„₄33¢PÓr|jBÕÆûÓe₁º“Â]¸Oû)”TO{ǝ¶ηYŸÆθs"÷ƶ>nÁн
ƒØδвßćJœ‡…Ô`×g57‡`n2—Û #ì+½ƶиW¶õA›AΣg´Ù·rAÝ-}Tƶ{3±Λæ$¡mćÅÅïû:îg#ëàºýмÚ%§1×§Àâ[pqα‡¿É¬ôiN›qΩ+₃ˆpºAfò¡¾÷Ö‹ǝy·₃V½ò§©ºK°ô/M;Λ0ûrθвζ,®
k6?½ƒ;₃,˜PÑª)Y∍ĀKƒÜê4ΣpÉ¿ºÜneDªŒγιw3¥i´›BÄœ·¥ûKñLh ×ΓßP¢FŽp²≠b“û€Pµ®ýµć;}нÛ˜Ý"(»”ý#@Wr¶R₅®Þ¢ôHSh381MÿÂùÓƒ!вF¼‹§jJāltΘm¿VOßÖœ_õ2вC~[b›βηfB,Û_MÛe¦eð.ε¿ǝzßoÚŠR§„ïoΩ±∍óZ_®ʒBoíŒj¼=m»K¯îí…нu„∍ª>eWæʒ|¹/t½β¼§øXтh=àĆôεǝ§CR^ìλ_&e)ò8”,εùu½и”`ƒzHå7ÝüH¢qì‰jµw₂ƒQRëÈõβgŠØ˜½NOí·₃¯ºd¬NÈëŠzW—$D)ÑƶÛµH·ìA∞ï<ž₄»mpªìи¬λû^8B\Ïƶ5‘R∞ÈнOøJ$н/òƒÝá<“ÆÁV¼qζ¾TMÓôćŠ¶1ÙΓ‰Ý’Î[Ó‡ εt'L!w:”çØM]R¦=¢èožÛvŸ‘Hö{ðkÕη†ŠÁƶ¤cHí;½íÌîĀ!Èí¶¥AöLpαB7ζO∍Î°…L L:ε₁k^ΓúΩo¨u«ë¯¦¼›B68›¸s®b|™H±sþ'–вζÍÿ'εÂµÉĀ˜ÑØмÇÿΘqó¼¹…ζò$δ›½ʒíµ®Ù”…—YŒÿ¾мvV¿C³³—∍ÔsεìzιÎwÇ´ïΛs5ÖÅα·‡₂Ûfîjº’AxO^\l€qā≠¬ÿ§.₆\!Z₄’i∊jÌ#∞qJôÖnºæØ„iĆ\yÀ«(×Îò¤Ú‚ìUKêµи/î²¾½ΛÄ×c∞iθúʒ}2ßŸn‡à||Í]ôT¬?|²₃”%.ˆÇN.m{Rø´ÁÞåD»¯˜„þηÉúkèÍ¡/η‚Ž°AÓÔpÎ·6UÝλí?Û>’áµ÷{*¶λÐ`¯íÿÑ:ζƶÈhë₅qθγË₂DCl≠Kk4äÕΘðÁ$LвGγÇw’I:ÓÒ6ÆŽÂ*∊\€7Σ_«λÉæƵ6'KñS/∊∊Ê×÷‡{i‚mcε\θ²¼₂²FH«Î¸ζε¥rå;W›Íǝj¶Àâ¦β}¼üNÊ¿žëO$VI*λò›J₁ΩU$
ëâk…Õò,3ÚVmn£FÆCÃC”Ûû×#uˆΔIÑ¡îgWò½¦>'¹ƶÛ¨öΔÙ3|4ƒ@‰6Õvãêõ∍ieýʒˆsŒ„¸¥‘l‚“ˆm*ùlĀÇOÍ[$jnYÎ‚Jr&²TâΓ!!I$ŒÒÆ;₄WF˜в|W×9DĆÍ!3¯иëKÔ6½|ûáF@ǝY~ŠZ∊t\Ó)m+±ÕµÁôÜˆoâθ₆b}Ý½“'Ê#«ˆè¦Ä‚Í,¸ÚÛõTaA₃
‹dÔsé)’ýª~pćr‰ªÝr7‹δý»nÕä‰>Žˆ≠£Ù.ý°R©°Dîf3Én[Æ¯Çš[¾c~,‹ÔÏ∍ÃhbÁ≠ÆøÁÝŠΛΓ‚tʒÂ©÷¯¯¸Jåóù[мÉa—āèΘÖαΔðA8eεlaиÕˆð6zr|\â`:ãÕ;phÔµA¼ÙR§ùdOw±˜sö%fŒ°‚]×CZγg³c}Fvp-0äι±ÆÀY0GÀjkëq¬¹Þ»2Hćøîmt’₆¡ΛŸÔX∊<1¯‰í¤¥ØíηOλ2³hÒÕ&ÊýÓw÷‡»∍ß£eùýŸÈÕтÞÔPι:œpžòε!λmŒEú0ê)ßr₁ù>SŽ¡ü„x×ÞζrÛÜ₃S›ΣI!₂a/lõLiHÑ¡ˆxâNS₄āǝÎ¹8Îˆ…éœ×.±‡»ˆ©₄4Õ₂cõ@ðMØ_θαcXVθºƶàW«!‘Σ½мÈ›—вā¡S¸öˆÝˆ#ÖλvΓ‹):Åλ€ι*1Jy}Ý‹IIÜ´òĆ©.<¦eN¾¢¢@Ç₃U4Ć’ÅtØ¹vô}ºdΩÒ",_^0«+‰¢ž÷MŒóIÔG‘¸\ë∞.-h)s≠;-тĀµ
2}>v^ph6Û´!›8õ™βĆ)k₄%§?™üçK∞´”×вBUš/³₆#~áÕQ+иw§Îe`ªŠ³žΔ÷Ñð¬ï$iúƒ&íó¸δÇ¯Š=вĀºÚªiCq³q«w\áX¢kÌØ#Jû"wØ·ƒþÀĀ–x-[Γßè`ǝPC;±I®O€Ć_i]ιy½a.ǝ13C/Λliš£?4|vƶìœÀ³y]ÇÊ)ñ₆'MåVÛ)ÛÆ~≠œ…ÖþΣbĆn|—.éÞh₂Øi₄g4‡»CðÎ6!„¹/ïÆYĀ™K1oáβöÀn₅–8qªC!µ«B™+7P]8Δāè2и1œàe´õÅƒõY:Œ¯Ù4p?îb JSº¥t–ζpΛ¢∊Dßλ{ΓËM'vaÒλ®ü₆|”RƶÇì¢∍λ–õǝ²…‡–èd6≠Lk{₆pkƵûΩì±&µ∍&U>?ô Ÿm¼oмÔotiδ·¯ÉÁ}ζĀ₃ćÁ09?†γ‡èÊÄsβPª+cÿKDÝ³lï|áγθöYØ§˜™~þE!áfuú@d1Ã³ôÞWζwô4P¶¾q½;e>ćþ¿ò×x¡jõˆ{U™“tl_¯bR¥|pβĆ‘εαβÓ„Z@Ø’ÉÙùY_Ú‚ΣÞεиåëм₅]‡V@ ÌðûQTLŠT!rßp8c¤‹=J¤ùΣ8EÁ°‰ï’ßž†#ýλ]тØÖ₃œ”`ÚË„cë^ÈΔKœl¨/GGÒ¨+¹Ì¥4f∊9§~ƒ×r£¿ÔÒž6`‚Vāû½Þ—∊Åvï’MØ!(α“?Δl'í]šÆΩä;Nü|`ûÑª6Ôé¾rÂœ¾íÇ®†0wøK]eœ¹Ò|‹₆PO[ãêIµ¿’1δ¹;ÒŒиZŒ;‚o«6ÀuZMā,q;ÓMîÌpÍ_ÚN¿Ì₂´ÿ~Xêн;¯¨ìÍ6Wʒòù@!MìƵèÄjWÖrÔÙcĆ‰*¿µ©íyÓ*rÔ–{ε—ƵÁëvʒÇ0ÁSË§@иιв0™4G₁₂²§ƵJI†(ÔāÈfÁTвλzù*‡V≠}Ćú$V&¼ô„µÅÂÎΔûu`ÄÂ¨_%‚X¹ö¸+©вñ₁+≠LfÝG(ι`Ć|5‹
₄µú—øDf6Ā/t‹ˆó÷ÉûÃƶÙ~„₅Iò
ò‡¾н|ºÑÂã₄ßºjÁΓlRQΓм2j∍ôÚÙ¥ÛŸ`ε|·×Ô“∍áWPÊÓи[zÁ₁3λ₅I9Àgδ¡…£¯ÃO§ ÒŠÆ)þð âÿfÔJÅðтƒýMNθ¡δćÅʒƶ«÷‚:PÀ ÒïÜÙŽ\QœF
!
X©мΛÜWÍMšι7‡‚”ùîα×¼ΩΔTë3.jH·è₆È›š=Ïγ∊m7d¡₆?cÎÔƵ%∍îþHëÜĀ₁£"Lë#î¼Ú¾ª+ÅòipмË:UÇIʒā2ß9Þ“—ûQN¡kqîøв2Ý∍₄#:¼óÌGýõvK¿
Ô₁¸ÉOÝ×òAe$C]4XÉ₅ñиÊ%â“÷:¯J~4½¥#H/èÅ§Q
ñŽ¾ γQ)á‰|Õráj}ā€ÓºéóúÌ‹º,oJóYΛв«õ3¤%ÎpBÕ‚{dÈQÄf.€nñ›и5a∊Íq∊ –ÍÞ²˜Õš÷Ef}÷ćœû)Û_nIÅ<½\yиõµñ{à 5N’)¬1·∞yltë!ˆç(ù¶ügŒ/þ!µXŽ¯ßõxS”ζÐ,ÙU:¹+ΩŠт/©M<₅›Ù»´i₆²<Q¾BÃÅΛvÔQ0—ÙVα+s@Þ²Ð©Ìc»#≠õ¢·Sā·A1ÙW”+₆%@ÕÝöðc²Δ7„Âæâ+ǝé<P3æJ.å[мàΩM1Ö∍b%–∞Aʒ€“δ”ÀXâ1¼f>ïÕÏJΓƒ+¹₄ò8T‡çü-<ĆàÜ`’δáds·т€$““ÅLÿ[åSGîSмÇ]θÝ'Qœî§2Øïβāážªм)þßWSÀ˜ä%ÞaÎmÍ:É³azγ™nIGćRÊI?γži¢Îʒε¢gô@.ë¸Ú¦¨6ƒï}ñu™U/PwH>Þ¼Y¡ê†VªßiÖ„U½¯Ç¿Šc÷;ÉUßŒ^"ΣêΓØ.]ÚåxãвÞb)Λ¯®ð·Γ·<Ï’d‘Õû>'Øß˜îtäÆ÷Š.‚Æ«æεÒN¤Â'›iXη»RlÃÃ¯þ*η¹ÑÆIæèζ%{$ζΛ¶Ƶ8’ö/3yā9ÒY3q]©zΔ—Ê₄UÑÖ¨R¾мJ)Σì¯©^›º9ûĆ cä…þ¯λú‹ó2Ÿn‘÷Ysàÿÿ∍нGV]¦ý)}ïÑbÔýŒ0ºðƒΔÅ‰Tζµć:ûu¼&Ð¢â«”M₂*ª₆40GÖÇÌblǝÉƒ94iD∍ºâar«∊Ó¯0¨A/}ć+∊Àã¸Ô¹ô®ιΔâ”’ã@ªǝcÖΔ—-ˆ~ÆÈç%n…*†∊нā×Θ\]'*∍–({ŠSnùZ‘rtÍ1††…ûlŠIŽy9šsgêÈô(fвŽÚyнmÌ₂δcŠö<ìü@т6θ+WÿµßÖ‰6–мüžg˜Ƶ₂‚þΣLŠúǝζñ%óYÐ,§R[o!Ÿã*^º;&Ûîćÿ‰δηŽYΛ:Λ;ÎLÌζLvhÜθâ“Å4₆DÿûCz\èºžÏúÃfÚB¦ÔÆ≠kd«Ê©ƒ@ì”"ð}γbΘ‰£ršΣJü½¢Àλθ÷µ¯“«‘å∞ÎθëYªP„UÑR`3Îó≠Gë≠&ùYT®ÉÚÝ{'γ]ø[мvλöÛÍ†?h¯ʒÖ:+%¼Jć‘Ñ 7óGö‰»нõ;¨V‘ǝËS€ÍM₃©ð·θUÊ$’iL4†èxçáA&Àиd›12dñRāн /ûéxÜ/ÉßΓ«ïv%’à₆)_;T¢ûÁé_?ýd„ïδγ0·ˆ+
l²éU₄ÕòÒ!ι}₂œ{©©šzÐ‡Ñ¤ä³V¤™~©’²ãÿ+þQtŽvbÎpǝ}þQðøÖ$³5æOƶÜ¡ǝaä₅ƶÆAŸ,,G®ʒΩ´ô·LÈ£Ãû∊TÉ»Ñã*¶HMûú?ô®Š$µ©ö5α~η¢+н{‹îι=ÍâîCµÄ=œλ®nìÔ’þ?λüš₂wYaþ“:Eav‹yWrŠ°U>ß$ßÙλB∍8> в²’¤Žb≠àÚöàk¤wPη†^®IÂ'}Ž¨öтEζÌ¿kÙ³þ2fΘF³¢¤‚^˜åå.alÆÙBub†öÃλ»NDqλγA§…Ø’ËÝ=¼dåŽQн[ñY½^∍3∞×£õΣok±bÖ¡3vCα3₆ÉΓïΔ#ÅèµÉ™ηÓØjÛŠ!TiÕk×₄Ë´±ƒéÃ³¡tƵ×η<ƒ™¾.Ó&xµëæ_÷0R4ÌƒÿŠ„Î¾ùи₂?™ýÌv›õ¿þγäγMV2ÌJcº€₅èsI6\¿βÜô‡мázyć4Σpóuβ‰₆™–нR²Y₃R.ÖL1™и´èÜ¿₆C×Ÿ$Þ₃Ü¥Ā®₁Õ(’m¯¥ó¤Ìβ/+.ÊãθYΛîNÝŽ°!Í¢°Ā‰~rÈ¶₄OEXKˆç_÷Œ+ûćßúŸ!Ωå£¿p:ì´Âƒ¶d—q=AØubˆÿ¼ø'w₄ι%ËJ4p“<₂®{6∊WC†›aEćsrƵ;;×öêþEćÜtálÛd»«#в₁ðì7ûþ,žjjβðgå®ÛŸиçYgmd:”ˆ%ćƒ{nä†k¯[αŠιÙµ+∞Ïà*½˜¢·N₆ýßÊ¯-Žñu=maáÑFKζ9вΛ₄×δ…Āζ×ñŽ£&m₃ˆnˆRγWĆ‹Γ$;‡Ý5t<©%Ò§´¨æ¶εËΛ?Ð®иzˆ)1¤%àÊ"³à¿hŽ}üλüÃ)Óòg&tû.†´k0‚×¹Ýö\rλ±"¦Diÿ‚\
ú}¯sƶĀ²‰°§ÐθÐïê™¿%åãØkÀ₅P}’'ýÈ47NæN>°pΛá©ÀfĆá₆È₅kΩiæL¬ç¤₂†ôåw¾õ/BQR!ÊΣM$¶“swWØEt∍¤ŠΔ«oγ]‚ι-cb∍åG¿?˜Â~®_ëÌíŠ0(YKRĆdu†u~γ¢Â‡ý^G’””dÿßÄÑ››'≠θÉæ¸¨Gâα-ËSvøā]ËâCðmLƒAÊåÙ₅=и®ÿmÌñλŸ6gÆ‡ʒUR‚¯2ªÙ†₃{tвĆ¡ĀÞp7и₂ĀïúfÞζwp›ÿ₆§;=
úΘV:™ƶOæ¶₂sû’ùË0VнN’ΓU/³øõIBDÍ"²βg₁â\ηwFä”ĀËdÂη},#ā²`SÑûƶÉå2₄Õη\£^ýåǝXxó‘!×§вm¿IÎ§Êëć–
À&-¨ýðwtf«†Qì*‰þÉ“Δá>=ßÎñð»Δ~JíKJ²ËŒà°¸#Nβиβ«ºð€(·αûƒGü₁«вĀ.3dCΓh|ˆθ∍iŒ½Lò∞gмā₆IΘ₅÷~C·+Λoв₃‘&÷\¬³½§‚öтF§4·…?Ý®þÄa'¡7òàB5ĀćÓη‹£‘āG¦w[ù)ε§!ÃM\mìÊ¤H˜piß…BÀβĀи)ùLĆÈ∞SdΓªíí'åx{ÕA»}εà₁çλRD7ê¬íÔ5‰¾>åβ›₄ÐHÊ^_DÑÞœ’þ₁αè+Ô€iýÇ¹š#₃D?™V*≠µ¸Òàé₂PZáY;[3Üи¨Ā∍Œ+fäΘÊ—Ý8ÂSN´£W3₆tœ]£½6ÞƶÏ NòÕƒ"5F>jýV’ʒ’ÁÕ1ΛÁ€ÌßðDθä—Ü*¹ëW”ƶ₁ñë§‹V%т‹Ùè
Š¦œ
|7ζζñôÄ$$™4ÏK£Ê½vÈ„%[_ÍùĀÔ¥†™°„É₁]<ÛVƶиT\šI¹≠fΣ”λg¸2ǝ| ]ƵǝA¸Îζ#³≠™Œk¤Dð!HE3ÿÍ«]æ₂êηaM„/ËÏαYCh¾Ôˆ₄"'’S9ìU}té¹т„õéæ4∊Ã@´ÂÝüXZèþǝøPÌØÏš,jV5β
JDç…3¶Ê²ΩYÈ¹þÓØHéÌþÑ≠’∍Ô‰ºö8Ê₂Ô/ÀÄ«±ý°]šñA¼ˆĀmÓ≠5»_ì3oªÛ½ÿŽ+pĀÊαâƒΘ±₂Ö¾ÿ4ˆYQ{ÂÉмi˜®x1δè‹l˜nÈвË≠≠†³Qª}FD
C‹λÊgS¥ζ8Xþ"°‡‚œe€Xû´Ïʒ ʒ€¹œÆpîõáŠтVâ!мθ~]\®,ζ#´Ä
н#Š$∞¼±†åTgÐk#‰ùβìï¶Œº¼d¨z
f—™‡‹∞§αÅcšÄ₆±åF3DÍœôÍÓÿÄ’kY‡₃CQØ-Õ·δj=…Γδ,—`ÂKg…`‘ÍācÞδªÑÿ‹jß∊ιgε5ŒεLl[@L®ö‰*ÄÒš:Ôô.WнãˆÞ÷kÀŸÅÕš!šÄÛáβdāì|¬ÎÚx«m›˜Óq±hŠøÔWδΓesó1ß`@¼ý“lÕβŸùò–.tŸø~º∞ýô+Sλ‚7µ¨_©‚˜$°ubº1ýTΓ?;Êγ₂₆sA’þšĆNaÖH¯ùÉΣÝdrY–P&g#”`Þ{¶Å†Yé‡βÌ¸ãÈHµвï½yzиÓE…x@ÞRši:"H™ß,²ƒ∊ñÆª₃1Íß®AÞë*Ö₆*¨±ÏĆe₆β¨ʒûf¥ƵΛjå{∍αa0yŒŒtbC‘ÎáÙa÷ŸPlB₅’æ‡ûƒ™NbóLM₆¿¨αOU!Ç¹Ƶ∞ÌrÞ8!éð"∍7‡+úƵ~K₁ΔÐÈ°ÌâÙUhi·<x–?óa¬§Δʒ°ηÊθεµÑ4KƵÙÛ^'7õ≠dÆ³B‘Ê\ý£nV3¯Ωηćиγéqcü·x-%ʒ₄Ž9и%{mïβúŠxÎт3=Ë¸Ú4-óˆƶ4aV==ß∞êΓ!Ö®?gS!08\ç”žLF™ò?S¼¨∍ûaüñ∞€oõtu₅×β£—₄JÓ6B6{Ñ:‘{mÓ.@₅Žp∞ÌÝ¶Ã[f,&ÇT?›@Z¸GTƵ¡fªJÑÞGJíÀ~3ÕºζlΔ ýåí ŠÍ¥J"Ç„yNú»ΛÝÇb/<”»ej‰ć`ï-xf₆e]_%ÞS%
Ò2§dα
8\¨@á¿wLâ¾[‰¤À´lJÜh¼ùÑÈY´ŸÚü—ÌΘ¥ŸβzjÏxΛr‚d‰DŽ“иÛÿ>I₁∊˜0Ýó€WΔ€)_£°q?çi/m
ǝžG~e(Ê·}∊n½“x¡ǝqCkJ¢XH₁\Ý3ÀØçhÛ/ƵIεβèëÈBh<ÂZ)obV¡êyΓ
øλ½∊§Ð©¦<_*žøzÛγS™íïB”uĆΩföã¥S{ζñΣεºÄßaC∞ηÓΓ~ΓÖfÒ63βþ¤W€€O₁ÕтB«ΣΘm`¨úÛ{ʒAγWÊõFoƶ+àvay±₂^…т&uεyj9'/:TšÖšÄ∊WÒÙαʒÈûδçû¡нΘ©OΩVηв—†θVå„)¤ćǝćQøåI0p&∞š₁Íì¿Ú+ âXjÝv‘±æuZ “„ć®₅þǝv*ÚjöËÖgтúÜ}"M?Õ:±ÌtÜ"δÎΓ0‰¾₄ª*—ÊjlÌ½`Bp½ôJ†×ÿ®Q3[ððí¤å¢êo/¶¨tpδ₃Y«/65\/°8¿Šn7³¸DÍMÈüS6iÞÕD»ιƶå·β’-]oGTηα–!∞NΣ¯¶jf¹XA:_îxÞ^тÔÀΛá}≠€ú üʒΘмóæcÓ8ñÙAzN»ò´^₁v¡Ä₅R;∍6–`Å®›×´2+kεÌçøaθ€Ï}^™«&†€U€.Þ©†[.-¨SθqžλãQŸŒ€ÁÉ·¿9sÿ–€¯9ÐMK₅žΩˆ˜í—Ã6äa*äâƒ›O'’&iĀвθàm^ÛΔćµƶт¡’āèõ/hδÌŸ₄Ø³1α¤àû₃Σ³__7¨н˜øé)âOPDLζ¢–—EKMÂNn1W¦₂)w¹pYм»òvNA¬ý'Γˆ{Irε§toÕ„¦šñOÁc»₆|0š%õ–/)†ºrEËnå™«¹ÿâeR‚žò∞åĆ?—#W(
ŸÒÞæ|c ¸K2¸—7м0ćá&
ƶи_₄îΓœ»x”ï™'š÷т˜93/ÇÙ”oβU'úÂšтäüñ@и;"˜èCƒ>X,Λã{hK¨¡ŽäZт‡tqη²¨xÌIãôÿä·èZ¬Δcúà²û\¾¤λSû¢º¥9¥+ε¬-o₂Ù"šëмEždþ3!qè¦û¾¨^+Δ
Ë$ć´0óÛI…K—ò—x≠ô+ãw€ƶüô[½}Cláœºk1¾-d"Ë]VVWÆ¹¦ýs!6¡´,ä@иûår@¡v∍Õal¯–θKÛh‰>ZJéÃYf9×ŸÐ×qbi°ζ∍UXïÂ‚‘bĆ@Q·t₅Å>þƶï@ʒ∊«k;”Γ2¿ÿªтñ\…?`ú…óΓΘb|α¥)^<(=Ÿ₆‡"~vηòƵ¼ā¾¸ΩεHnÖÓÍuNdø₆{ƶa₆³ĀтN.FXàĆ3µaeâÒζïê{¥3®3±Ù÷η:oćв“ʒβиáfηóêaKи\ÍS}ćhÇÒÝ3å´wZ¨H|RαÓšÁôu48I2ÍS˜xΩ
óØ Aˆ*B%FÈj¤o5ë₄{þŠùÆVÎΣΔn<¹|\”¹ð₂L“Á5®мx,ÐgŽÜāŒ’Ex¸∍áRì∞œ%UœÚ"¤äqñˆ)₆q€ºÎÞÖ–žl2y¬Ö"ŠýG₄Ôtн₅:óO{œ7gÈËÚIðÊa²ñHªS?æC₆`ÌΛF∞B)ÏÒNÏpΩ0çt]εÄ₄«— 2êœн€“ƒÁ6ā—›èe(θ|'†A%"´ôγGkg”ØöιÂÜÿ2G}Êbìмçλi:¦T×º₆¥₃∍8∊Cë¦ÎJùZλ}màKaBøü¤„&uê›«ηo≠vW¡λǝƒˆO9˜µ¥+$Q{—αÉƵÙsÐþΓΣθ¤₂ùv¹_ÔGªθ
—s„73θYéʒ₃òWh‡,îNʒ/Ôø∍0Ê¼Ê‹žÀвýô©é(óèÂqmÞ„+HÌλÅW„k?"í’Ç¨ζ^Ωθāƶ¦ÆÚ+ZçмĀ¿¶&‘–…8Œβn–|₁vûŠË\ΓÀËĆ¬±Èxø¯ì•4ö
```

[Try a version with the `ö` replaced with `вJ` so that it doesn't time out online!](https://tio.run/##JVt3U1Pd9v6fTwEIKKB0EUGlqfQiVZQiRXoHAaVMiBoQRV8TlBpM6E0gvRGY2SsHZ2RmT/wKfJH7e1Z@89575wWSc/Ze61lP2efcvqHGpo7X//vftWrjn5o80vX8Ea1HSVe08AiXopOrjWRMpNPRLtqNGei9Vn@8Vp3m1hS3lQT3hP3R4wfFKFxih5zkVZzXKhdNF5D@/l9tm286q0paI5/IBToTu@S99ywjMfIFnbVeqwxZ4iBK7vumU65n58h45wFt0pa0iaN82i4X@/QFK/mdK6zSQ9N@MxmlJ5zM4ohs0aV0Ksx/9LQmbbnZ4vRaPR1Nv0sj6eu1akXsX38ykKGbfkurTyXMl3baK6At4Rohq7DhS9/oh091rX5fQS6arROHd2jh@sOGtF1p6PSvlo6uVQvvSFMizrArWqZlRZfQ9kdfKHaF1Tf9Ry9Oxuik5RF9rBdumg6ntYmia7VmkhY7rlVYTxT9Jyypw36vdGK7ZqmTzjxpwzcu7ddqdQSZWsSxdJAV9VCN0faL8muV7lp9NEozQU3C00ra69n1oLGntIR/vr5RDO1Yqf9MbL6kMzqJlU5yo7pRt1GeBfrvFR1Ie7fcFG6BDRKvzun3kpms9c/F0ZWmMeVSe6uafo6JU@zuM63moo6ucWFCt47JQbP0nc7pvJrLZhLmUlq5Vn@gX4qhuLK45QXK6xFOcj0gD/3mojqDFKfw0hx9F3s1vmmxc61aJlURnSrezuvZefqRJs39@YpXLogN@laf24IKXqvWcc3ERLFRSrrBic4s@kEaXFD3Gl0T2MwaqeuEs4Q8kdcqfUXJOPZgl44axUka6RwKJcel/VEvAOANutTSkrRiB798M/mK7lplvFbt0MIrWmy7ew8/vepNQO9oNfgGHUUL76Xd76wWdrJlXqvcmXKzTVhpWTgGM0l/Z7Li0j6eKExylXbChLHHN0Mf8c8JeVLpuO0GHZIB3fX6z2glXOzG0yJ6qaKNl/0D0oQ7iQv6BCBaO4px6QG5H40mXWn6hTuzFQg1inPU9if69Ef/VjjwtypUzQwA7Qt3gTgla2xRmlyNI8@gdPrN0n5bHAd1Jadjydo0fPr21VopSnwQWYOi@lQF2PcaHSTJzX7c9QLrWut9/VgcKFppka7RRLHdIaxYRxZ9UHTCIbbJU0CmwvZgWpQ6@lUqNp4q3n5hRgebuNwewK1U2AAAr7D5ZtImgZjVqzXSh94SHvSAvDcyqgeFvQxTjg@to5fW3PL2xJT4IrogNaZGd6kN8Zuf8oS4xG5nvm@6e1gu9YiLqhL6RT8VXQPZEvzm7KmXuKFbmqWjNes2rTYU0eprsfOaTmMw5Rd/9O/oVx@tKIYysQuY0Emf3BcmBpLlRYM4/qvN6qPfirZTnD3sEZ4CcULHwKFqx@99w6ianRcHj15X085f7YRwxQ4LrzQL5hjn83/q9odk8GkwZph4sZtdVk9H0tMQ8TqSzCnY422MpOuN8PrBVfpXl9p3ubR9j/R0lis2BpgCTjuFbRQDe6l9VgY0zJJNmtsUAy1drQlvcQn9DvRVnAh3izgqxt8PFcM7zNFC2ONI@g7OWRW2XOGgo0zMM508UM4xBcLT0y8O6MjvFFgNeepTsmrp26X97rVqqYw/N@v3lpAzP8zvjSUz2q4n4wNumYamq8TZgLSL84oi0pHVN6MYhD2elqWOWUrPg/j1JfFMBEvb8M3CkNFUbuUuLRXVlYmdh2jiXp9yTqsjTM9LuWQfp9Mu@iEd4GHsa/rSLraac@l3GqD6m77QsU8Vgm39FnaxnUn2wn5pyron7SXcnq@gXNVOYXBhqrRhirvqgTO33O8Te2/EIR2iKjuMDXdWMmrtFs4hcdw0AY7NFaYhOr8JxmPU0zxd3EQf1MJGn3wqIPA7LWHiZuhCLg2QBb104Tb4oDlMMsCFF/T8O4DcZWwOf0O9axQtXYhz/9lIlbjIFhZhwS95kQtDuPbRO@miryBXzP6JXB26Sz/pozSheSAPtZpWW@m4k1loOXOspL62G6Mx4JvGpGC6L8RuDJi9NuQFWodPdEClOunLDTRqIJ@s9LMXo7hDS8Bih09T@5ZU4vAWLdJXjPoWmFS1QkeVBXQgbH5nLB0LszgHRFfpAy024xodzOV/tZMJ4FtnL9ZDhokJmq8ja4U4Sp/AvKrfY5fhMWDumeKYnvEycmIX07RO24@hyidXazw05xCTT@Tuoj2aF8ZY7ueK4hWnmYDJQj9a5UiuJD3Q9judVh8xToyot2M8CizrgYJgqn5jrL@nSjtQO9tOhxj7AemUFvqMCj3O7kY1CrqSaAtgWaJTmg4r9Jtz8OeZUVwtLxX30SaTRvGSOgoVqkUJ78nNBnGIy3@inUtb8k3QUXks/sYyP4cKcfXHIZcrPc3SVguhxNziXsL8NBf4@Sqc0g6C2B6k7TSMlJvm/@g7QeQgYLEjzZPijM6KaU5cAM@HJWFVeVG4lRkfzAcY5X5lWBAmdqOLxeEHmW8n0kpVT6/YfEqabHqfzWOxCgFavPHmSiMX8sC0RnB@NbrmFTuPbgpXYHr3yA6JXk6cSLrUZmDGkunHCPzJAdkAro7XBCxeaYYULXognGIbM9WNDWFYrzQ9UeTq9qlopoTmX4Z19tYEfEn@YIQwV9CG1IWE5IUBtVrSgO0/VD@9WvObJ6pp8f5jMNZ8SKI48TvpsIAWkoV3Ais1Ps34o6@ZUgwvUMDhWtJF9kQLE/1AH6eBQ9yxD5d1AqtNk6QXXiziJs3dEIdAzh482QeG4vxtSPkKdm6raMwEtILA3S0YEtqPZFB4xcFUv29mEDsFQ@kHoacuacWvPb0o4hZ@/UjxXml4MjZpOQZ/OC2DnJ0@puPWRPrU@5I0QNKMYnwpzpunbrMDXKBvPIfv25uIJwok5sR69YpBrjJrrQxjmtXwMQ7wxYlwwvSRhVwvwQCfGjHDvmnaA@B@ShP6cJqZ8lrauhtRmB/s05LfDU7U0sarVLTkR1p/Oy0IWyZwsQwpIVdLyagwXa0NkT28VdEyWa3U0WL2C2lpE5bmyacj/Xfi4DRdKKKGVDVxOaTq7KLDAXEEE7UuPAm58ANOOu4ZRmlQVmGUq/AjC89R/wfx4oQp9zcc1zY82m/pKJGeBGFpR0N/RADfXtKNBiAONcX@f4nN19BM2GLQ6Q9Y2nVaKJWuVEXXD/yapS1EenoU7RNyx9FBJP0aBIjJ9agcQ2wksOj6GCZmXdoH0bs1NK6cJXUzLwQD0xjbTbbCjlyG8JVmjDaKywEoNqkYIlcKfUXDMAT7io4WY0TAuHiuNDDI6g9J9AMXaCZbBp0W0VIDBt7U/LwKs@gG/A3V4jAEkIazZA80i1uiI34zPJ@xHDiyowf6K80NdMczws10RaaCV9lZSFdUfP7bSZYkV14erYGyzD7cM@YBlL8YFLghNjJoBhupTPJpGHofh2kp4M4nIaZyn7Shtxvq48RhNGNxAzVyFGFaLHm0kIMlCWctKGp2PeZOe@QQYJV2558aNt8WlDD5aKS@vz0Zs2vF2t0pmFTYetw8sgsbho1Lx89w0bsF@Do7Jj0t@s1ZlYoxFqKh1tyYIiP9eBbtd44CRF9fv4LFMgiLcg78OaBNp9CEk7AOcl9qI8CZFtCUFcJyohgeojIqiMGKOOjIHhCWAXE4WkvG52KjC0q6dCOfPKGj2KQDkn5OKqQPlW7szkt2Z7T36o@@NDtNmPLEcQnq59M0dNRJ11vhbYz5o49PzI6Vq90d8Oub6UkTI@jNEbqpEpa3dRDKuUgyYeU3i2i7ilYjgRDNFGrC3ngHSncuN5t8mt4J9C6G9mm9nSVvqQPVaEsKgCEbfP41OYQ5zBUL96upwdo@bBTE9yFtmQmU@/9RT5cyIA6yQyC9h1n4e/S90roUGZjQBL8zHgsyvEafbfQRG7TVpGLmTmg5qT@djpuC88uRTrYxSTpp75erYgND9Jh@Sc849v@56OZII2mRM46BdbUGS9WXYZMzdMQfnAekVDpiD2cOyL2Rf9xrScYmC7vG8YX@rksb4uo@Pm@KEMzNEZWP0skarDh7xFkfwLvQN9whrfDFJ5Cj6UlpD4Q/DPh03P10mB9pYe3dw@B@GJLmUnEQ3UwXBY9BpJZuOplAISxQansN@rcLyf2wMUXnT0LI2PqG3Bkt8fReWEDC69XSPkrWpFL4pfMB4U17/Qi3OEdQMNPimDB2EvLleCW@DnYe7m4QJ01lYnuin/HJg2YDzZnZv62/yGBLsYzFLpOrpiFgJOQmGAA2AhR56EedPtZhzVUZwUDXKXmeVRQqhoqQQfrVn9IswNWuh/lwIC65mfKEppn@TumEL/kLLlRluEFe6akDEYFcUQkGi/4VpOEzbt5Mh/U0KxcKFF232IvNySGt2IsGK34R20mt6Nx9sTuFJi8Oik3sbYG0ynnyK6ywCmDwwDquB9zXHH0cCdwS1BJyiyPTWrpc6L5Jv@sUI3LdPm2lFdPZxCuoG4JOMi60L84HSY0Ac47ZmhHHWGjcKDkL6l7jdy7SAhku9Lu05CWrcB6geIHrx6OzrjSsQut3vlCQnlQrfeIwmVRvXhT5pm8PpJGuCKnhSz/No5LFWPIXNhpWuph6Tgd@bxqUZ4@OaD65GmqEbJwRUkRHgNQefehEcB7EypabuUWnUYheNsjV77eki8LvgcRx2F/VwiXL8OEIvj8TR9Pl9FnsZvid0uU3x6HdSTng84C5EbuXtvw87OsW8ejMttJ0BXyw5x25oridwPQkDIA7rCoCSmblocREIXB9BQF53ryCcVSLvYZw7PE5KmIXzmixjzRs4uMPHohW0ufckq5XPs0EEoUriBOHjc8LFsj5uDXZp4rFFLpA3RZiz@ih95i05alAQv@YR@YgNlEIr37vBMjsO@68GTgOEO5Ompa67rJnUuc/SwhEfSsAswwBhC6@krYJJJ1FLska/81YXYpp0vmdL99B@dXTiSwMH/Puk6oN7eLQDvCc0PsSsRuM1sEZRIIWT4Npgy5aaSEfmz79h@RF3qJiCJJRWjme/9UiohyysK6klpIK3wRhrdGy4q19puieBoUEPUc5zmCw16ppvkgxSte9AGGsMNO76FiaEOPP5L5cqKDDxJhOjmd7gFRA3hTjQ/oGKpid67nXgjWqNenNcPJobjhv6ZjOc2Eq15g7psVmaCEd3oClPwPln4MxsGJzRz/I5nNqJc3k/dX6pmHr7/M0rHH5Pc@KhbFrAJdB3k@ANs7Oo7I3UnEBC33JgWWwjRSIiyCUEJd30qcSRL9FMme@DsuuS3pOn1A/MmH@58KJCYQcqeIkfyoJjnX7Rm4s0PpR7D4LIhNMw3mwtDyLJGz8dIJ@DJKxcxKJRn1EOjR1H/dzYwaQ2923@/LJUiNX/WaU1ZYotsLpa38WfIFqZbyFZp/Rh1bkn6NeAEzl9jvvNvJczw/gf4OZhefhlMwIbT8w0Y4nrZPkQCjVkQcq1NCbRx8fCG/tWyzZBgyaxskQfLcYAxspjuKRvmbX33YP02EIwLh7i1ww92dtijaWzqExz7GJEyijbQxWR4/4999tWq5MFa5oua8Y/qljxX7Rg4AsuQFBj7B2sEUzP3gmzrPoPWzI6ggtPIvjui9XSVP0UAavlP7jE8Vm4bnBXtQGG@Ioh51xZCJEI2Too3GR8Ax4XT1k77RZmOXCPc5XakS8jWg4qv0HpYm0kx9D22xRDXK/KB78OTvfFM4neLPrmX@1qBafAQasheo5bcSLs9ZHQOkP@pYvdZdaECkPlDmlgiVnl87uPMDAG2gNDLoMM2FsGRKOf2pcJiwAnDX6WEgXL2m7PIeOyzka10GK9DeBd4BvNwEMfgIBmSajAhT6z3iMflWXE2dpdHO9kb720HwqfRKWxncA94eN3rwc30wZzeWlSxibDrFBX/9qkbU22siaEYPojoyA8L6XjOk7mSTTG3ynMrZ0NPcRanhWA0d6AAKrQkT41cEnXOuVgps1gyxmaCZHGn2qhMpo60OhWAfQ96WYOhDF9hhtgqjWmyKh/yeQ@lPhkDrheICEoFpugf6hRJ5HN7GfX1j68TDCpoYciiGGk4sG8NxBltcWQ9TUN9H2jufSITxl3ej2e9z9PAo/ukBYmjw0a0/aw8fDkCBXhf3SlsK6Z49NfOubvk/amsSBOrH/Ti4wOObQi0p866fYK@MDhPxILPoI69uv58MG933y@DTBzRx@dqDkJwiZfPZKloRAXl8iR80QmndBF0CB35tTVYes5Y2cRMO/N0E3vIo2DiN3eqkFf/N5eYW084FbKshcnEUAkBsItIcASxH0IUocAIFJyCI/4X6@NHUDcp8utfeTOh7zSZebNhoH8WGMoE6cxIm9zNhJ30w0/6yiTbRtARWwimPpws02Aqcjy7SZIQ7@6Jvh0nnDd640UyjrLO2GY/k70BwDvu73Aj@Lcqm27mYU05JKd2tcMZT3kusF9jg4TPPx/EH@zw55uhVDnuJ9e18xDrUhC8@S9Var34zsv/LW7@0JiKu0NoPS7Q@gqmcZ/9TJ0hldTZBOPhnkHM2nPwjwynnb1dqlDV/gHsOpwsOQ@w/PuykcvISpF7tlL/tCkJs2o@qFOy0C9vYYSgDdP5VW6VC8IK9UuZpGXwvpi7QXjrTTGuYjQJAfk1DNx2iOJ/tdLVKwGzniG6jvfSutZKFPC8RZtqsF2JoT@4j4fOinD6XTSWlpkkscPTYHoSGb@XQGiG@QSnpwbQcsAHzNGrdtibb5zO4rfn1YIw5KeRroe9mrROiGBRfPQU75ZIiAiasA5D9hDvTjN6WljpwgkBGgyY4NoeCG9HZxAvfwMzU6XJzl@2b40t@D75Elh@y8EI8f@pAm9qrwB6Diczmz@XwRnz/uB0bJWUlzYXxCVQhbb6C9MXCLMTOCVH4nhssdn9BCpjLftN8bHAvV3x@jtVis5xdG8JBORsIZKgaUK7IhrQI79cDO7Dekk7clcCiLUlvihONKEx3UDRrdr2QK@wGvpA2Rrkn0T9GNi32xrxjf0X/Ma98xplvCUgUnCrOMtKlaxvc26SKazp8NK96RJujMH/0kfoJ7ddLPMGG5SzslMCNrwvhH34iJU3/ET5pMxXn7dg6fBMt9eDaY@EKaFZsYeyTruQrwGuwj0CHsuUVYtjudJ0AxhAV8mv2uNE2BGDai/d5xnlvMxkOo1gYdZwONHx4qOo4dvcDpAlfgPB0tOVP4WHC0ppHglNdSnzSO4JtvqwcRBE8rH9GvMKB4WXqyMCkpj4KhnGbe3ZbibQo8dEKPEZ67xNZoaeBgtV4c54GyJqFoe2T/p34CdH8RF13QLQudJ7TKpafCAikCxazUg/m2aTumsRtDupz1polbaaf3WKSn@PEA4GfJ5HPynf@PB59J/1CctdC24n3m974kU43w1mNZiYzJRRTJJjf7uoSpCfxmTBzJlqZE9jqfQMoncuEGHMsen7tyRHYQiLoTVs4QUtFBP7pokVv8WViFCTKwzwlHGIdhcxel48GlFl8R5zGkixjDBUDNDeSIK0uiL/gsVIAx8xUm3uV3opKByO2lLyMs1rDsGHQLbUlLUVUCfclvFm6WTHibvaG85FpxgQi0xs7XCIYwvnvrmwk89LC8kWZ@kqTWBOKTzu8tE@YawL8shn4WxuOXfj4Z3QN8LvChbFpUnGHwXur3@M02kvkxH6n8uIWy9YDetxHdt0AY5tjoGPjUTekEj9BxMen53DSE5tGQU87op1ODgJsdxSh58ryArQq2qmijoQszwIFbcYYgyWxzEupPhXJYCaZV2DE2CwMPM2npTRO@cwGP57w5iotIVzh9zk/qB7AecCA4Hk8GiquzA9zqbnzimxkavLSlpcH42cGt5/gFrQ2TsZtWW2BzDm/4zbyPUzq6B7Cf31bOOztRsNM2LOGYjTjM1m5NW08Ln/xfacJ9M5fa8V6WLyDy5KU0KQbpAvJs0QyRb2SIEt6rNTZCxYwML7Y0J07ugMxNbx72NBIm@WmBtN9HRlllQCyysdnxqYDhxYDT3IzoCTz36r3SlElLNackl9SFpTEJ6O8OPxD74YiPu8DRHu0IOyT8s1xNh@4d@53vrjSR8Ww5DTQXimEwiIt2xTtJZzyE9D4SkDS3RQyTBxbAIKxdcawSi9A42LPaQcyEKVTsPO5gMVipDSL3pDgZurTz815mzFOxS/@Bl/@DFh8wXi/CMVubtNRFMPAfSycBhZvY8WzSvWLaKX4kTvsBASNYQ9UKR2b8/1Sg/tgl9ztop1Ac0S5mlKXKgOSzPQp822KznpWF0JzcLAoDRlRrQ6PVtPRkmMV6C5VeEId9IHsO7647zU0cIrZzxEU6plw9JY4bMDlf6LdiiLtVU1Dm07S8wbXfTEmwAam5gN76HD58ZCHXt0DHfiH@fQ@cw7lvgmuwuU8oqlPs5dCGNN2BKoyQ0zddB2LYyKbTnsJLbSbQvU3L2MdDDMgxXUCgySQ9ijO5DfKnMv7VVpbxo9@TBBi6Zcah@v34sJ/P64w@Fa333wsMMf71hNytfAg52s@DzFMmdtMeou5yqSoVBb60l3CL8eEhcDPoyUWf46r8Xrb8UlcZiw4jCeRlPab5UFhrcxsjeaNWOkafMkD1uMXnFlJLx@TtG3Dl5lflIHYPNOATbScEBEc6asVmPXq2/Uf/fAwCq1oK4ceyfnOPuMgD5exit4csnrogUkXcAea8dDo63MpSbXhGR1F8DHIOxoNDXyDjo4co6VcyQUA9cmEqn34X5EOmPitaYPFUOG8USzNSPLIRezjQ1C0IrQlr0ubwSdW0OORDv5jElmypa5@40kgnPxdQtMJbiBg9u97mP@PYpcmDmQDBOaayhSNarvb5//@5zlIEYUNHYFYvk/oKq8NTsZvET6Z20kmPdp3Th8abwngPUmvIuutTgQ50rCousYnv@6ZzxM7oS3JFwr7vhtD7otoeSNmc2Mq9WuvvoF@4ThZcCxbpd0aSq9DHkJ5dL2@B7B/Qb/p9E758nH5kCs8kRtPAHdmVnrLH9@gAgP9NC3d5lM4f0TbTr5u78F8uzdU3PEZv1vnYCKLJT1xMtBfNyfWoAyWfES7FeAN7fMzcXxXFTwxs8KcoK@0DH6UvyFiT9jKR1oDJPdDs7DwotRWisARHDluuTyF1eTFIY7OaFWtY0dWBYb3JtA44fAsuRjl@XGpD7z591EleWKJl5C6sBAQfjxkOJN0vaO3pY4zIFl9wLQq0ccgZj1/BmEbLD7nkrqpwRC34gmXaC4K@7yi6oIl7yA0woBjyD2FhfHpD3wqgpXPCO8LHBOvhLxtgIVyA6wI/8zEwt/ArDpzQp@se0GoVv3VQUasY85D1Phla5SZnWE@bcCb80U8E113a/ugzUY6v0n5DsEvEFRQtHMNjOg3JfZKISZ8Xh3W0w0e1B9LRWISrx2Kov0lTTXY7iGfhSoNWhCIHLZffp6PKyWHaFy7eyjrZoNY7SRwK3mewHPET7ecvoIzn8I3OUj6Mpm@K8XZn1V1pDsp/TOwnEpG@5zCU@zVQOxdgBzeQiwt9wb9@5xWChvh5KqPBTfYUDk5qWohF8PiA6TDxsyA@1jNlirMrjU/VQzp8667wNNBRYh@wtiq8cAbe6H6UbQ5o2UAiWhImvspPbOgi6UpT82wcq/3kP@uAIh2PxSMM76E33VdrvTSL6PiZ18FLMQjLM3Ew@fRxUDarjYfm2srFtrSnPKfzUG4FH/go/HLJ0XPyoAbf/mqDA8mcX2MiTT8do0pGPkeooo0Q/5l0TtXViuPb3A90PcjvvQEHyU8IzviJiYG2K9rov64bzB4uyO0RnQg7xtwN8yX23gW18oEn2xIjH1Dia7vY4cdm1OMDs6SJtp8mgvVwbyuQo0N/@VlyV03gAfT77Ge0dId@gFqsnQ/5YbdOWm/jiq9IXdCGn19xFpj3TTeDfK0o5XcWPFcnpnt2TrrapO2ugvhe2P0yoxCMwWkhCjqhVYypSDjWmGokh02YkHVyQPmQpD7ycU0ILw7ZwyjNLQh/RxMY96@0MiYOezDnECjdgDC1I44hVVbD/uteD5Elnn69yoCX4aeL3aBjM67m4gNDXcww/tU5BS8HW@Ela3Q5n9qv3MPY7zWw/V@5WgsTp2@ahDuevBVSl54GGFhYTtWaocwAjShGn6a4kX7mIs67YFI3Sd8yiBrpSiPabgTOp9fHAVOkaEMNaETFTye@YIw2aTZX2ACQE@F9@w4GSPcEVRvLoPUyxdiRGprL/vPXbWGGbcVUmEjDMft9PPFzueNMFOYwik/BNVFiD7365tMAORqw/h4CmadVbF/a5GonbY/zswhTY9xbRatoh5uyuS1f4ZCWG@EInaXdWYHzqGXiRxSsEbhtcRNZCvnVMHEh9qSppDKEuRGJF1X6MkjrKSGYsdNQXJiPKaPJfWmbKmA6XYBtmRWnmL8NWq5s7xCOB2OoRDpZGiEYu3Lhr1acwrTPSafkw7XvSQXw5su0Wn/zHtkwJS3YpSWLlzhXi@Hc7K1KFCdyXzp8M35@rr8/0IxQ6xi7E86D8UHx3vc7w8d7@CwJptYwRl//qRMfIgA4aSXpDlmuNJf2pMaqhw8Zdut8rhOCwT1ObysPiUupZQ7RK@eFT7nU5vRyzM0e84WnEUbOhC9g9vrINvyGZXARpd3kiVF/yCddclbyOH2HXV3C3XUxGfiE4u0PFAgKiOzzsvV2BM1UpAOWGS@EM6fi0iaMreIgnxUoB5pNqqlEjI@b34JbCGZ3QL@Dgdx5sZ0fSjAD62@LyQ2FXwUVzjTFPsBahed1JwbFN/OKTu6MtaJDr@sawmm9PDyItAlit0WaglJqxV4GDOHFaCEh7bxk7tsilbB259NaO8aAj5tma4RV4YfqZywzX8Bp2wocw7tO@jYmVwcBfH4B7rHCIwNortLFozx@GDA7d7UWh/VgBI6qJQtnZAMk7nQgnXY7YnuC/qCcOVOvb4GVHZP4dG/gkf4YZ@OB7K58sfE8F5epJX0iKHiJdttpNfbSlidt6N8ev6yU1f6A1C8i@5qq@MDurYQjcsIye3EtNsZI6zsPGqKUc3K@o1VpKefO/aYTQEb/xqeR@60IIJtiu3yctVBuAmVuEMavxmy0htOi1E0hRv5sJW1yIu55LraqAznuqCQQtP6ps8QhvrbU8wouzE2r43@1mQgIMGi2p32X9mgyjDS@DQhAPab1nzrijbS97bx/Mza1AtT0M8CdSEbwDMvShEGcJQ8EYRd8bvR7Ueb9ErlfJR2wUkCSCl64iiDG65FiyzfzR@@beQbm2s6L64/AejnQT2PcjxA@V6KDaeN5J@lH@EGyiXbevAgOHLSu@/iJE/AJnRyJopVOFOAz/Wz7p8by1yZDi9LpRyq@8GWY1kKxlK9SFxcwR/yI5SAqcJrY2Q1G8r7K6ofaWfNZORYR/o6fJb5EZAu8L4CctkEHfbHCLvaG@5Gm1O9rxGFs8t3aWHGawkeovfdgCJ2QiyLs@aw8uQME9eMx4MvvpGxDJfi44U5dX06FdPBTNV0IdlgsN5Fq7Z2twvU8M7WBjsdovR4rX4D7A8lPsm7CFLmD6ewvhNfPzxx2mkmXAjpcznxXLDxkFtZ6lGlEBFTrY1kaBpgP6l7RR34S54bRtiZEd8EmfkEbnI38sskRfZusZ/9zGBFIDkeV@G8MrTPjG17GwICXS@eAcg6N3nymOBXWYLi0T8IhLu4PsY7xe6/i5D79V1TAk38u9680UJ/fXM73ybTVGEVbbBawgBK2OxEd8LJm2DpDTz1wu4Cm2S7hm/mR0jI/jEYoa0d3vihONqtLwhIvTSi7gV95fI8qWRoa7ok9P1IvALIfSRslpY8LpV3woQJu@qSgiNTFvfHVgt1X5Khw9df4z7g8I8WZ0EjvTam70oznDbLjHu7jJyXrsI1wPiU03Sw8/Pw6TjGGg4RVuthINivuwSf0uRfo5DrBXF3QxmuOXPzmB/Pctk8Dclu4UX0rSGGPvE47E83BwlmQIJz4/T3/WRxsvzEiiG1lA@/qWOoUnfCM8TOGE1z2Jj9@@ae@WrufGEszgRfj@qS58iaAq1aMgMEW03CG35kWim3vZV9qHz2/DVxsjrcXQPOMiPtbL9g9GocHpENA@cboSx6E1YrFbvEjshfiSC4043oG5CNPrcC4S085hnGDH@zfF9vR/M72nT72c8uhWM6h/@yJct5C54khA4EXkDz4zl59tFwIos9h6Jo1DhBczcPsF3CveYzH@PzMGk2bowAFwH5G1pfCO5ndDa@mE@6ueHF@pyWUPtdVVVVD3vhVc@9QSLIwCutt2sL2yEPbgxnCOBJ4Ebmxm49pddJZQKvt/PLSi3w@yKppvc@HQxDYxYGmDqioHZ@ufI54qw48J1xq8mkyngnHMHPBx0d0jpWcZPxl7yAOu9LYyusSQCQX4gCVNdVyVnvFTwV2yALrttQ0AcBtR9Y/uPWQMcgZO3RqBJRphnAhD6IOTgixLbeXfsILzr8pbiH@3PilvZGdgsWn@qcujnn6nF9eTRS2xtfwAFqw8AkdjIvtRHGcCBZaJod0pPZBzVG5Ncw0gioZW3EbCx00FvidtTRfPumbaQcetKwS28I6@kLs5U6UwZvq0KFpsr5JSslLwOeu1sbkfhC@uRSceaWJygp/SrOdYqvvLr8I@GEc1swAsdNUgfM25ULvA@GaqGURdXEoVhfyWfv0XXHsPxu7Tf@1AU1rvml@K275yZhwBp4Gl9ER87AuvBImeCWUT4cHyHSlicSOB5gC3LBS6/xwQKecdye8xaT9DMVdvTmM94VhvxfdSCVLybiiu9cGYvxMK3lg1LlG4NGUKw7K02knGxd7BQ1efYp7ZUXSN9IW07d@uR9Hu8N1IK4PTNWHQFpwAh0oOr4oP6y71NJ0MoI6C4mb9l7fks4JcI0hMzyUT5ylJaerjUdtiezShYiyRhcJOZM010RHIFLk5Y5UsVMBfnRz/7Y528/O8/@fIRspc4e@5pPrhfRM9pChoDELrHPGZ73rEW/4OZobKunoA/BHqoVRev7oL7VXmpL7SEA2DFXYs3GsCg37xO5uCJg9B8Q2pTNwEkWuEeFqoIUccSCdQfjgEC57L1E6YY/Z1b0nczWAb7xNx8V/tbEQA25GHCzFGcdsFwgIXMp2XezT/i30f4/UAz38xHo9OheF9NBHROb1rvRQJuRleNc9aa8HeJ0@fld4hzSQ0xe06z/zqeBw7RCBpQCN7qQgkph78e8TLCnkQSs/18IvqOizTwMHa6LZMXLC6KP@G0l@c/7//vd/)

Just base 4 compression with `1320` being `ACGU`.

Answer (score 0):

## Keg, <s>29872</s> 18008 bytes

```
‡1229769972262440840914727645274345682540406609304568884862926340793218455130887715162068129549355321803218173656794410207421983304458198367214649122525663673362934345290524357064085900270191341217902957576981212048606874907939849315096416270570685716443130572591739768026241351892812265951851301494384951132692442813092528368279619996972987050485879686207261053889017001520140272720162621630329395409296065427861604527236404743258286157654372871028806778211438395242253891572078183604800612931937826120598888382248388598280083843577247656912674622919842712535585589649603509001095863547810817077902398964957827180268584103438275390041624163348921595274849969049661923023337666521725858745368146713074157363419797203831210504834818978164052880482258159540114728150425625301732942056513844023648924490089702569897942372547984473520085739435720506236035510642685776972243391793417082460246010780599850479767673240905889526401286127570068665468508243120173758717818630146928614751654837642669482601249225952952208411970090930833845733508094571347955589328109927131499990380676370464247644397486822444748015028671071135744999340934890935615460997653385677393947073970908818567393639815738970653113217409016741696529755715756612050720426679067698110637288092453898586760691588411082488082877613478022659054608787769528410260185454336843014741113111357556292755532164832239454333585244411641833325316642270862455913274654562884236651257150638140537828859305826045194963038168347590998320806786930182572946514083553404524066032480665928208697588268964081909305784920080726150955846857962652779905901747407981428733780288150791287341673230523341015906347352187518560205372794350517498986080348613358855603142671700687618353662837496155184294344070723732045539972453663753511115115441046047349026147438036288023280233941426159301911665224804172906544584304217904465847046843191123925427520910132509935862816760055239020768906897682241542165037638348904204503433237534948568438544144382338137750589449243356326582507310952526081284152972731597062614880387317348517949871009897850682867538923980203686226074685634256224033307799106132027504784090187800086328504469313742512319975477982387330352228492180810077802884040825704770764544038848431145528445360947849645485340995675140338420516795194391875739483010596185498720573908486020752567154506672207145944313397965555119387825631247278735639065637101895134340448526110625244876623748141868893382305418001655864333085224521184960426661306172015226321027556110813663364068754961411966346349411886773402140398449647788595798838460036470066973426514948829648806555700167311800114711897868437368217702796341769755372420321373403514711116489842498534695236481676350558132897889110650754011149703583979863449424041382281400518343058810460496843485272410822050441441511212394733858551284285254446098327175968966002783040825103026543391039706133799343678703208954903255241621200608188708430102527704592701870512305100099340069959599088597034315398192432762170758105915057585697835061206206187952271582439132615650902906482976574888711304264321759903752906787646241293237089219270860749922386060037977668584177574304628217209473882223389349951344906759874508318966387457669822008687511144961634967108793339929664100796278974873878327095609255951824928893965920351074002213024061767930437574552268890649909229763991595475859168835836933470999820642068628431842663628451184715883077507150868753875337437950031504964684710957735309868918584197113517588308957564510387438935010261473638823258379397638506933211151767971378787761423017878482951398194512688841643893011841062343852229355366472988644268692977994614530504607585315445341477296491001766570932240810899739717357361563912261219584530474733977149175840913869203077868527738029877546166166432908090016561037367864038092286759075731681714950635078219186504354444241560203123263666792544215726956471858914244341055717391728851666538189075684716491700897488003748060514620874277379944815819147411284878113359661583123550024889823524693919751077046816953854745273428710032594158442701344072661883700217905006853043558454223244842645922213592315235238605239307564515699925969464312169257542510629380376289699109246323913371045368058363020865737917164125837277951175058024387607813204625940189991741457166888725597795289112206512198318642300419476633713431162394621226393503378310547439167008919270347114247832674009826133029154197123898550175442521189668417197139076479812903755015303569157447551638166061999464754675091229673945632405202828293488805337738683639111772228708502836612311106755158464539016805642828008162919177692469018934304153135028855958385409500763594871853431581137706699658988624314079157707209268447384078490576022213685500814019642828526410364603187086325312898413766685585038590154916842023314752007493596211119125528517741236693378225630581958903828930971985078899934359913031523060714101672940008237291504837770871802588029929218636755669349244212204996382915841626768809051060707503177124597652328805802347116632506559549550536920961894878378904738276541296485879993891559627126913473579341025083767390345408003146512152038109025143195352522745053378455983723827780237837238741396431841753208753396437681356002675964329698466286597112076479184718665945091483823021613136959520044485440274147672636376419622908376621472807746535346942095213827654307322738192333534228609841977854661763599570908681186158036757487239267473767181283914272513633323484105525140357502476305757164428816124965832038548025933594112073619327388299693947905109116066350975032674941389877440928039698052227775574389570376988726049295387179328419000749668146326696179823994603574403859958527275371131480165492902736948668958348304366292745211500479235246796184202289411410009515755037444590152757880503714305913698964576822042570078616145163634245089574906263834860341805376900817028250919717742813526508755423552198017018670641069740068470905435866558884696053781019360198643139821064537089750042037620028635312528313083166827629631036697727749147139639348162237420389581897742294175480035079396401038240139413882424141629478577251818865688344550943741318127682360806270357869741652697224751179520961257926117226273558893447779127064709276856058308795167279967873293632154833742592535740479428489951963543809722191325071721723324312622305760373965154672523818492186110300611592053731664802501915528789829743117255663743501448302833846336502068174239853084008285143275389601577002030263857435827935681409957489169945791666255713398510484919186369202426073007707146988570196237426512875053605605995529081543402736727878108214303729300525899319512232794208241752608540511125866795951441871903707416397254362102509899851491326779905801738949094974847381106903685377347031001892438663221595586110264199731475632622251152520827738261251523586293230599928996989353410358353266854741858865780095399615918195227633388051537832176131234826182152617318914478873108398354011729097485557910383189943385740570007132166851210727701693896999347383074156857801401352901102152180046473693605365584235011899687114080994442990837995021535581910310154557794176345572355435728202518133359520721305554113571067340051237645856278460868192110770159396109076577591147107315505115136602696081711783789116710518017974363046228031929413669107940302397758723774284502452359619360049551476211247209034110254241661959556006726012111219128319184702526502090268181415250948370180201714947357095025743788292030876532985955173474005940647567890651888787759450155165883311895730995923545351994256284320503162917451931090323632596882667154390729229377700681257431096734835739517031397977858566922642394812507633852522420538211700928508658964492150850563425485241313631127687609634388796337138809154504245860397457019027353963848150342501600523439936506044920733019589409820696342862972223317655497599375153379330980255105930769488730449139276213883440082923285236070344837062327374844649846917496258067008903360541158653502196890273228987668677290973404701148936927045713183183158588510759602020652529635016512571162284608953744996249015154033222434288068053077881274663356912139763543198405832948976122905823480094459747808919921077237953408630169752852893254030578981309874522656768526686649375802082005033330697652484357099894000021158778170975768691165375749054011304964746134146867874986853314973482070628690240527424420306057912660101437539721974883055909494021879762081356728883480379339165791801284812640505952170045036260466010536310667489709490257617081716739352716412220216401996100084022374111751400596281927095572170185905004448463672684304060348122451036810325970923367373073188186963599708728447932616138650243662519279135105838808011534579482828102800296650358235067632445112676021648248656475081155776249910329161534969336044910724519274139330350832837082023462580593643318924303758601999016369956453154796367650435597790747576089985549015244141303765289484856862092107494359686499323238479464509050939264219419796629056169294623231487984881763267569651033188934682979284910584173020858886772012991953799794722787179221101951319223490613937049894742920948421085009344616675906546232555921705727764182625468946369316011229790907639354238881085727145482476029655616840538527256696708053428368862393341857155701411704974884508747051510911098633175182904611994663215247553395350005371365318723005822818609901050095931810576849197506852533441939824362961725007603166131754683647631727510166349649066358581728998521727545626838783528804103132743214654339162823197402586586235383613230305381594420022884721333796177758586462034697808300605043341619053815800237472697862915457251621636575269806320367107543695610121254091812024374106900933590891515953552043848458177968643788843136680935617643295298398640503434870468906209147596720248723131682159547757622198229263771407213194735612006902728603770147376628360927526161797630530603690034447271682003840393520690097021925098087667282664440931516233026971238079053545019139288054468782319268177009537797481752446774111551021641116654891856268527514959161302598065575584335492382041976312989999146250772465621404446978494769112419892326765524648672234014494435976632485810536105283914531977675290500485751307234888481777860639751542882739444252400288945838987100569447119815870767181211087650850666115804077465132916628832643690766575588511847652316389525843073421428356192480775301036338489926079172190125078487968112274369651712083537529095160834474164678444712147276161398494147381808523485886499785811528347245957745703022413670799660856570012663197157127708589791803932642290010855627392615861028546524135920485901139574288813026253085701418199764075679032407473371812028761031113514096024307798693248484115484161893279165955397353619798342897413574440652394103462847093238420518491622396613278440084980285714274001119521212146583278228646516163035751677012268515567393483760637457544410363713184585509209192672838657558877635929516771381262067784415674449672276466698511687982504455688259872115537430517139027883960527698749137216286280715606919777679010367022624054261554634951964881068266029634898924209581095797538957899705669608759871930257719696779492339295194763542770331334961298635643951779009810946902628555532768733707115739223784728286843155094517612459832086292646728150421237127170105161975294862501769639182875895634297441647504612483090734673439591712887374742578272532235696776749852037048402701352055012810562120052397945024980660429979102909917375065564886040021049640925865661577893143263672186374964207419484016400677315429719550320529475120081318648475826319287994362908078728962770414767815869768223532020093272938623238565125180292373072588362748850880404250107115575398062802365849657711348085059977171566144425215789885706504750719574694183920277604790792286624985793487190462359905536540173451571940984223672261645007320696492501582811601875077157916324742007396663827320962777461955531192844430475907631838222195111347286193556030568465955336996366563856122177247344212208931431400372260054208470700900351196020816763626384653615266939614946284247930038955954233286046123503189134471532171426787801011828222588859374352209598727869510299018617061824915817311554708385480498560549423287168103299737881363155684998467032297793573412125663448155535461617620964844267812597562453145133678593888364349239324452843901169376278440494006708280343470877886727585933470053157064184164967774305382613652820890095325391887780182405720626555238608133213634283353471668899595201536767293354988511826546065595075680956797960478433434908300996053109018439290257384548288437158231830854273701596776950470082875610184067796182523270418553707883657963253499854105151754323927390151539300645161184103742636113067606636133856275349472361843631623612298286829320692057035529546408642788995573707433461276181097119158639256594238473854020771904489121350047678116647319070650732144622731694809421966278783285613568370218856319522518996251413816308827154285284711639989567155283168910492999693824446966857279729047977830398926897602106494818605837079923134825226329464579559956244144425297755651628210873886038677297136031660110018232793051217827104478380326244108671507201134719163826599852703788303358664182159728204087147649998823390209094673454445008122854919873681364771859722271262463456114955354657319885051740330759000869148683388222725396392510884284446484329562449708272443027543470127407739300687294721804583374540175668315116189513496418434201549599254809054682664748593917699844225219965421291805059917426842209244482234400202949266962976948822851699438210343277551423978180803875910290814748612294319805100991904522856851837338104159244877389292498113510738287261454240293455541894224633095217394522602936026551595456061623661055902927654091676630774418532523764391562406526618284469283958531843383259303240132162357122398345971567831417472430897951652559344881573873996452198982547630644259944662286263398481295731183797404355119020247001156674683412373110729584936346066326213743589945075097856922859015944551532516279411580409309394261450432272618407573608749062492115755003698739641507119268668515893435513218194246993964380506202595337870405689985091484654042450874003212029473421931412898578225297293295519407237805898116649283143095650627213156119510869364346688550366196240519226659161294197925973913409510972990407098495159885875804777945532162753995223345036109201654687459456591393606196809149886707961265162289712454378008329177774675628056913157417126669097606244595079396967324721549576507113794984870842666361786811311865762551606483148398602644844825558569258346194489589085842393455215391175561752946483780311441695396417365452917522463959898689659333538791793949654399639185816790676211214068656108899527458234059366314058388879543488371632913732788969940937368504473501786986773365428667723720916638821659445640469398388962347290599454063607744745571805014601269538730377829300322663133877008320829439859107658259785108209896343560390323005677882719027146326379826159251171576295202499368640686310542262472609043845233670917320245855561169422377865202960746333772546406182883287541831927837935583576069660821038475080977252447563461361850852642662032325964391810968358866316742144383224544451227046370105060845523184286787713378882546932972822220128516062439441890242789967331212694311685917031718978694313191384266353212105707487229821923323032673000078575471699706507763178058901849276692475004816539171323042565311423874782330003955924722773348602607047695466471601192421760467702254146760255278279163336548916738455638465637536082472285959223577060897564490962537496415306816394096942325066073922056375707790548296494099167311479240271569316621052018931558381501932815658903419723649109491158537987316248870664081476476264511996920185665189875159032161640159865376689047492001364539705880246615093400775341953007551201729674003847988935873320276363017432257699672409155448929277093975879817861131498758623709713029926471495582203283923859653894659999814623604636195344129368367860032476800876925643907666519023356389165088253392120552435167137609934229001557465495002030686271752262217161353807448582706557855440872932521534039868047328045617063634479606443723016725618519227821652481859877183369748731862958606992384709357130914442361412922130243410108156434305481004819602951852625297232370503472890607339128246701106802868299060924444420135825175266647128856927582691029230334509106919769340616149411506814850317322215207375613821136022083879670436517972766663072693186919704204474484981993713400251506049312726997346290074492759487337880701132276062210655057712231336387711178432079399208205815351137389313337091613182861577812254298862018871924111826845600464063439989735396291011529560167528065950637500987861372089704732791613930935854866181700200087868305741424698178924593925177638460799580985998301278883696749013578784132990997408172499594144562232279688361488259332859248194538662348838635342877394019481042377896015885883404556714012021646329691784011102529606151880573960699369837270873183884252945998867402542244827314429978951774956571942095905643679254249910365886648549686213109538986051849100092500547340540282377946152216680949887291394185964711492547963610708639399134980370331893710394372066674969594078716349344478782286683652767031119675111289612264494837076623388691032737810685506949000809314842426663931142362967980455039298100848261281695058045407818844911633694339274288625555792278179551330379936312258623724120398285533716838615191536413875991390555211733795410547570590869185567375692854831305764043350203179834861820548781447623166632670524066647593604499613317348602789064196218557457377379413970448035596466935435963713098458127286282897934502723506839961627176376626811495816403261216698183042966003381399570625255232284634895543020717357270918687650772426273049378345804166561697502079604713889169578987578427979220699491692901498897730594446864357937693924500018707947751267594207670427323785477079662805081137938317031331157   4⬥
```

It's not that it's non-serious, it's that *there really isn't any shorter way to store data* -- Keg wasn't designed that well to handle serious compression challenges. I mean, I had to add base conversion just to make this a serious contender.

No TIO because it hasn't been updated for a while. But [Verify it online!](https://tio.run/##jZ1fr2XHcd3f@SmuHdgkLcru7h0gQGQZaHTkhoEgAYR08uDogR5eSQOPh8qQtJ3EzkePcnav31p9RqSESCTnzr3n7t27/1StWrWq9psf/@rNm9/@9t@8ff/m3Xdfvb785TfffvXu7d/9@a//6pOPvvf269/91oe37391f@@Tf/PV6y/fvn99@fnP/vpnP//Zfxo/e/njvlbvfc71@HP1MdYaY9x/7308fvD4Wv8@fj5mX@Px//X44f7y8Uv33@@PTX3k8aV@8Pj/vP8cj2@P/eXoj38fn5j3l@P@wePPed90D@G@n77cv/a49Oz3OPr9wb6Hc3/38Zl7BPt6uuz9G3v490/Hfef9s7FHe/9z3@7@pf70qblH2O8PdT3s49OPm837F@8HfEzC0uf3w90fu0fS96/vsfT7p/en7z/XHut99ceH70Hswe6v7hHq0kPjm33/cz/GHt79HPu6XePc63GP5p4mJvKetnsQe1r6HvPY970HoOW5V@Ae/T1Dexb2w9@jv4c1u8Z0f/S@8P1b9wPe/73HMfeV537oe8am5nvfqK/9tHua76e6h7T2A@37zj1dnrR9wXkP794K997xE4x7wTVL@kfTvi@713/Pyx7B4xce17mf9v7pYDH3R@4b7L1xz4lm@/4lpuv@2J7XuedQ66fFuyd@j3ivpB5Sg7@Hdi@MlnXN/fUe8n33x132HHRtZU3vPZ59QLQX94D33e9H7Xse9nzuba8F3Udr31b7Yz/1vs2@5z4@e29y3Tl1onQQxp6rqY3b9yG5/2HYfQ94P/X9ea3K3q2TDaBtsx9rf0yHpO@dsBa/qN@@V6nrG8ufeHzrXtT7F3UA9tzeI9n2gl/di9Y15fd9FsZjTu9bNu@eHI7GvvDe3LYwnPJ9wuY@GLrjvjuX3Ltsj12ncenpdaz3HmGXaol0nO7NsveMBq/51yYe04/kjTQ9AVq@e@Pqwz6V21TtxR7b7G17x2U7K7efYh@J23joIPV9lveG0Kr1bQv2JteJWTzs0BRp/@5j6FOzz8i9GzXPmom9VzG@ssx7r@ps67KDKRr6tX0YvSH73Ltbh2M/ie4q06ZH23ZMZ1jGQfZq7xN2@OLga5vsPce57bJImhitDj7DF9kfvh9rn5q9HlM2ccnma7j7IYaXS4d7Tbux29Yt2ROZLnky3bRvAzF1@pbuvldSRpXd2bGxsu@TMXPW9vMNPeN9xHXYV9dZ3//FquMGNJfyR7JJ95mRF1xs0bnN@N4he33mcSvbBsvw7Ce574u72sevy40ub9uh7b83ZN9/6kPbCGhK9yX2tca2snsy5t4Ve@a14l50HcR9jqbNeecKa6zY3oXh7TKkXWZ16LBnK0/82NJ8y6DN/Z1t03VK9@b0qvk8ydVpghZLvg/ZHm1WefgzXlLute2xjiCHaWGL9h0wavbYusueziWLwh6Y7JBhA6Jttf2RVrMvhgHS2Qe2axdwGqafawxmBB@110AuAWy1nfroMcoAoCV/oF/s4DbMy762NqEww4oZ0TbW1pJR6Xgc7Yr9CJiy/cX@jBZkuxSAz@r4xxkzI8Ag1LEdh8z9FKTbHhLssQ/U3sKGmd3gs58p28sq4z843F2nfj@C3OL@kqce/lBnrXVyR7ePw@9oX@yvPT7ZHy6zTc0@b2x9gVifxiVnJLgne4vfmHiBbWu1Reyx5tIB7HYbfTsTYQtWZOqyc@NdzqmO@5A55AMsog6Rj9Y@4l0LI4y1DEUGV57YWLuzziHyP3tht0vEq7JOGo3snS61/R7Iudv5dJZGLhWEssbyqfVdxrmjdhbXnHKF7Ah8hP66bcK2PQoJOqdYc3OsPEZ@O6gulNsxKsJ/6@xhmwJBrM5ukdnFvxPRDEUl@wZCXwJLwiOyJvJE87gPzQ27V9eb2mYbpu9LLW162YwEBkQwxCIyTR8Z7b1CexqXcYIXZQNbfXKbxGEztcAMenI95e3xdVC7EMjClswFaMK6DkOulaM4u80oIHhx6Ea8gO5BBCZDBHoa3R5eP94DWz7ae6p9/mKnMTuKPbU9tn3VwDgjk7FztLsCVvCJgJtCgsHdenAHADWzisXdkH/vnzWAghhVgUfFzToaPcchdqMndmSTg4Fl4gZrwc7BKAvQzjgFzdxYsah6DsIDAoSFC9dSDhyLjqGRhja2tqvA2MDr6lYEiduO9OU90wMD5HG8eXTAOSh2H8SmBHE6nhN03BUUyr3aN0wOiE5v12QOI@u5LcCcNnWY9wFmUOysncjW46orVwdGYQ034gFLHJs/7FvHwkwAR2zVoACEO7alVYyM850DlAEhYAaE5esJZ3Va5FgGsAM8j0mx9xJDMeUaOueCmLb7oeRXuiPGPcNaVVnwzvFP@Aza9AbClgxAoSC/bJFjuiezNvGC8gmawpFFlLfSvDF7AmKOjPzMy@u4ZFdNB/Ag8RRDzwpCHoJ/MlMKQAD5ciKKaMaye1iya6J9OvFlzBTuL5tldfbVns99sY2mFG8Yby8O6SJs9q1WNxnCedrzg0@ZuBigrs/43sCKiZY81fBOAk504kZZr9V5NPCXeajFGoFLdVo5iTggwREQwjyeifkl0OA4AKuGyCs5U@DTFBQZnlmRLfKYgyh@g6Q9bDMfQDofTNNChHHeDAsv0n3Ohaaysxceaoi/WvZFCjP38ZOLSHDByk09i40bCw0KsaXy9u7dUaUP0fYpsmIiqSZrBwDrsZDdUBxs@ORthOa7MZ6ehNgYZD6It@aKgc9yG@oIDUxHTKD0vpjzbW9j0XFh@E5vPk2q2DotMBCuc35lkXQOdPc9RtNEyxGlnHpmWBCRmGgO4GJfnoZJZDGx3hOqd3TGICIDai6bwR6QeENkSVdcsAKkO0F4n5jPHnvQxXwuwLAZqIGvxdsOnxSvWzeu7icKPtHbMj7pYkTwXMvOne9wNke2m7bA7FDo44lfF9/VOf9jQTCC0nh@TJZsu9ySgd86w9f0ZjAD2gSzN54YD7EqY8Cm9u7ACu@9ur0PsFAOBb4j@wrEa5cCBOpM2hwHNyoWMtkr4onPYxVW@E1HrbJr2pnDsAomaTOGhEWOTuBe7pncIHoKCC9D3CGuzw5R1xwr4cmykYoXSNAOk6oYbYmC1GlVIkFEiqh@TdvIwugBAQFCpg4nRbZN7CoDW0luLHsK0cc4zb7O@sIWcm5FBkGF6QnB9ub8wcmDeKRPqPtNuejiWlORWguSA@@p8waYPCFYD2Gv8@k9OXN2lgGewho8ZUhunU8gPgCHwB5mZ@DFYfaGLjUdA3YT10QHJgGUX4Dd1QzBui@GtLxzNJlYC1ycLCJ5Kk3f0wosZ4Gc2FiAD8WfLOLqBzZrEPBF8DwsqjbxtIci6jN1kbBuhfU1a5NfHOuYd8/8SDwb77NM/StdwncCTW2blwKJFfCNqRlmX8lMCQxPT47SJYtbabT8CJA5YGlJDHZSINiMpZhQK6bMk6Gg4Nkavrfjj2QRMa0dPnOI7Od6cA32mDy5CFvfQJaW4EQ3cCAcZhI05cSbfaJ55CGogNHHy@e23bax27lAxxCqkP6YDuHJEzHjA3vDWZk@MYsvEjMnxxRHTPQHQlJIM/UAGHfbpilXFRu4/Z1Mjzwu@Vn2mIIvHT0yCvrXxxuebcDnKD0ES2Aulv@f1MxYRsiKvyeOAzApimc5lQE7ARoNt9hh1TM@0eCDEHyHS4ByPcbo2VcwSDEnigIGGVGZFkfH07MxzLjijKF5DD4Hm1XJ22whxWiCBGw@WFAHJbhOos5hMtMWzznYbpIK9MrFOQJdEZwzcovoUvRgLICgctIlpHjMrCuJMYhJzFospdWSS8CUCBuOpC6Svx7EGSRexzDzA9Ajmr3nc4hOJbqe0iZMcktrOIaa3mjLOU9iw0U8slgvuyzTMloN0Qfh7niEBe5l4ANzgMeZfcQV2kR0k9XyRwexT9KCx1pNU@yEQQeYmRYasFTLY7MJXTkKg0w/mfxktwF1An4LWn6DEwVDQXdO9Ci77WUdRNDCAwupQch6kKcTxAdV6EgdprHbZ/XwXWOY8Jbxhy0fyQxpb0oEMi3D0BebRwTXO7zvJ5O4SMGxcHCG1pyQwiATtoxmMRFC/SdCOdw9FKVZU4DZsefLaUSdcaKbKW5G2D6BEyc80GbClhzWVMYIOQGKE9yQ4JugISwWGcUxvBs66ahc2Y7ZagWOvMP5uZCfRG0C62k7YxQxbU@43CRvP4Lt@wmuMf1Ej8saCcjbOZYRGdS68gzrpEW6xQNOuhEJKFIK/NtwfXi/yUdvUCO/1w2vCOFNeHSDISIi53btAhY0@QDP9RHIh7pkDSdcl8jaBR2BE5UnYx8aDntFEhUrH2XskakgYtWOXuiXEOEQkq5kdTXGiaUaxDrDOpBO7jJaDQ5ityUJbE1IDsktekBe/2CVde5HTs3kySTneowWDJSI0xUBz85ud0eahOlSK@zwdxEo9VD6EN07pJX5YinJxjrEg@8bBz8PfIpWbOt3AFPDzBriJkm6kMo4gebwnGkbzgWLbRi2i0/gF4XLQjYlGASEE5k2QYx5kuhJ7JnM2Tr@ddZS02aF3AA7SfBiUVfyMuiXRuI4vKG35rZRikSgB1dkQ9PyJGj/YQ6@@xACUe3SbAcm/m4BRMV6iSrBPiH5A34MSzQGWj8b8gG0nM9Utba8p3R6gbyNdmAHzzYO6QpQHCNkIxo14Ot0PkObTtkiIap19jIiLROxzoAOZWsXPnEOP0M30WpUPw@HJmWjXKn82EwWLBm5YWtqdOHZsJwkITzBmahJNqK292DJh5NKy3tenPMyz5Mw28yh0iOD3CsRkLPRepZhTc6IvE4qJs4BKNqxtnGVtGscEsRocxr@WpZkhU@3nbbG4ijWrLYC8nJ@nRgbzkwks4fghWzLOBl4Z9OGvTlWYWBj9F8JNYjslw9nzLTjwE4SyKQ6wGk5xeO/rgTR45j8SR7bJCpmevDD7MWBvAs@fBG04K00ODMtk/gBbm8wjGnYNgHNnNnVzRrMJIkdFBJp6kmNi2aiQDInXJyk2gA7TAs@5lhHjDPJm/QTapB/QJAMICIFRgaOQMz51xHN6YK79ZyZRoaQAYGQgjFmBtSJN1zhILqFdDBqSGud2TLR2lGGYrH6cq7TCkC0OobvdvsOjafp1OAG0UbdNA0SpIMipiUk06x2cJZOHWdF34ce2wkX@QzwvZDYQDqxkoqyOs@2EUNFaKZT1bPxBk4EXkqBJAdPO@RwlhZNA6u1JAibFQuvMMlazUS2h69fhzCApQQpwP@SmLMXtisYyUtqB6GgmOgNZEVOJuQIY7DrTobAuS1nTJQeGt3zjxxWYcVC7GEjYGs5u1mGbhn7CuETfG6NSpLaoah5RFvvHmWRJO065z0qEXy9WS24ZU6QTqv1HUzBJNc8oreZPLvj/W6fO479jdud@L9u89IZEtsMenycpAACncS91rMv0gIjaVNARSI/1FbDUh4S2JZ/kOQK3kpO6lgw7zfUeCj5Haookj/BO0lXiw/RRlncO0Ltjp6z3c0MTKQsk2zgsFrsZAPQJAxcDlog8RUcLyfUbldLStaKKdQJTuPK3OMdBs8fNZ3M3ZzHJo2kWg0cpJNDweFdsUh@geGnLaFqM5wvQXA/QkfPICkCW/N4fAEIWc6cLJemdBRS/MayoZ5mkrG2E62LahWc9g2URWeCKsRLgHCCAMzEKcm1hKvDWn2TOyRbCIcnBkIAY6wnVtY4xZAjc4WyZcDkYODEHw6UdxxS/Kq5GvGvJMh0rY269PA4R1T6nmSL20lJUfPi5HG3gKefdC12YYWQcWBCJYxvLgpVwhBSZwSoBgfW5KsAZhc4DCKUUK7Yhy5qmeQRLKXySUZzEhV7tvZPB3iatDUZapR6M/oFk1r9CD@nYY5zmGNYuWlHuAVghFuaymFA6vy6OZXlVLWzT/1k5A1DkAP0iAWSWjJZeOoG4hbgS6OFI9BMMrw7427bt1JRlIQhQKWnFCL1VDFLsO9HJMKW6U/43YSg7hTJ5YqEE7a5WwvGhjdfSIQ8JE8LmUfS15oWtPaTSOc4Ze8/RysIgPF1x18/FRlYuwk84kit4Pj@0QiH9dE83p7TSUncdLQ3khFynr@TjogKDM5armxkH4bFZwqnEe/sJ70KwiDDiA22PizhyZzRMqEaGYEAjgYcUFkwqz0yRn8yUYQXbOlJ3BGdDTmnpzCU/UyMPpBIiQxfkZ1K8IEbTrYBHYo5qWjiJuyojAL5npniCRZuGmCOI3YVE59Irc@IrIk8xpGUGrM4MWvnQLDNDkG4T10MbITcSwhLBLz@ueMJFT2c4pLhbNfwwqGa3AZhThN9LoZAJUvuxZK4dXKVngQHQ@I7u6qadIsOBepQyAr6BRT6nnjaZtqQc5ppgy1WHV63LGQmG7Oo71pySSNemmKMcQzsGElbqJTMouaUuXWSUdZPoVi3dIt0BrllcfbT@XBBEvDfSrWYLOrCPpAHcAykbJi8SKhuGL5F4hR0jKlltyph0KNNlLXbNTra9xbF@DJkasXzdLNnyDunU1gxbsR5pkhjMJFhiUvALNjDpw4CSzjMfi@LJoCjBJ@Deg3zDaP3VCrNGHiROQpzuuMt9C@EMpqEaYgIt7ZUvWFZF8824KcsSlTcigbVANapb/QLMHNwI64pnlHQ97M3SFA815XASPWAHRWhRoU5sv3Qivhh2SHHPvNB5QnIanR2I5Q2AzWzDJ8iUnbMUyA4rQtMilCYTtzUAlMOwnRYFO3k0c1ME0DFEEU6gJ4Z8zRTFDaJW8GDwyWToB8zAA7mSF8TItuzy50O2FScODk0YKrqZccMPe7yDqVlcN8OyIbPPYXAQrYDOG@Wgntl/INtzw5aTkjqN@1bgOt4D6TnglKYmFSY9zCJsm5WVj7nZGyJu2kiNrI3A1LZHqg/KBs2XHWgLyQwTR7OEbamhyuNDG8gexziKJxWcrr5iKtN05IiQ9@PkhGd6bLma9s8tEvdqv8ZIMdoCBhIHALMiL1Q6HQPY0T6J3RvXTAY4uhZDBOWew4kUkdDo/w@tME6qewejZDt5ewjdX8zlW1OqM1xUuSuz9DTzCSLpafYcGB4f8jvkJezYzcBGSJH6IB6sYkgYprh7t6I03oQl4ZoEV2XowYEPror@i8dg27dNDL/xGrwpz06dJerdnuWp3JkqRPDf0Q0i6hrZd4sfU5xCLu3x392Z/gsS8FyS6K5fIq6JSFUhozuqj6KOGdMqKwcUMrljTwNqBzWqZvs1FadVh87mEZn1cO4U0wp24Z03XVpg7prx4gjNnCp1haw6qeyGi9FGlb9GTHi6XG1Ut2eRhBUuM4VMdRy5YRJiBRizmyG5Qx9B5JPpFBjWha@rLkZCdwcfqEo7UFWuDjXFFAf5OLvs4IIxtRcwfpukrSIvkXurtQBR3veRflQMb1c8u66rVMbpqkjqyLzuwNSdE1bpqSxWm3R11OstFxqZisynR92VW637zxANDRlZFkpvnFVxxwn/W6lmP2Ep1O9N7zjulOLUjN7xqiU76cijaykMxSu5jLPNLBAVL3PkAXrVENadUgw6Xnm1C@rBFx8jdHj2d25xQEU6WBHMZbj95w3ul6gqulGF5RoGzUNy90MqlJr7NYCfYartiOxhK275GiS5EhBj3AzwZnqZLGryXjEEJGOP9sj54ucwEw6xznMgUhVROaEXzH2o4bepYMhwPqT0vq5eIU0O9kkCQQGMnNgTLDFQFCakvgBW@XmHkLtxBEpxbY40ElFreqTrDbJzz4sGASrQWj3lbQ8FdgwtZQBdOpZzDgJwCi/7c4FLtAaidVDIKpdyXDNnNV7TzValuXiR051mss040PF3a3jd@cpSlszWryTuDa5aedIa41pgRw8F7t32G85eh/dRRInHckvWhyMQ6EI2/yyodQBsU4ROMhNa6BujsSlIMg2aBOiGpYT17NbnLzFGUko3c2MDBe80iPpcGTTxVv0kRHAJlq0@nBSsoM0ROmCOULSuYo6meJlGa@Ld539QeoyXfVHjemMAsVo0a5gGIclwl3hPpIsci8mdouTZqyy1QSsjVcNtpJy7dhZF5ZMJ3EtV@hp5zOZH0ofQK6h@WxbplNfA3YPJa6VBOFJnup2UEI5pc8oR3KDqURMlVVKz5@0@Cs0FSfFmW9VsFg5PFzFsoIQLGwfFk8LBUGwCiY/WXHnGZxgAA@uE/5jOKTqGimt64mulhVSc0S4gh1NwwcrDqj5XadFk51E2MAoq9wP61lyixPnN2d/Ttda2eLKVDp5OJqz5jAJVtd7ZVuu1NGk0NZYiDGgpkNKqCyZjI9580hBp1uEdOtIKCqJFiJSX2TnMhLAAbfTcbx22H6IvKg1QzdazztcLeRS9QGpDKJbKft/ks/PMydsKhecOjM@oOAczJ6qpshC7H@Hi3gnwG@cusO0EQotbtJM2bD5nHZa36u3e14414OyRunegLjCeoOglfi1kVpHa/Bpy3EoNIQ80VeEtUiUbWW1hBWksC1mkSdFTUSvi5nj5rBRDBZmG1/8zGw/teyKNgpSfjgXPSMcA2pbsaLNY@kZTeJilllFhH4uGrH8MOI1sIPSi8O6QpOmC2bbaiZHpfyRGkoKsILi5@l7N045AvXutNhap2fRwMnJm1qu4rnvliC7SUc31u62JO4AuNx4qT@XcZxj3gn8zOnJX7hS1vQI9SLroKRu5rIbieF6VT2POL4/Nb2w@JSqSvfJQJM50rTj9BPZkEJytkhdR0o6nuV@rnFE0WBOZwYJpLKBbMtIwQ2FX2PF61NnAemEutMNUdJMC7g8VtpmCKzSoACWbqb1pFtuOGan@ImmiafanzT@OO0aYP8sE7ZS3jX51CPrZAxjpJEKTprMEfFZHR0TRL1Xp@osKcF56s4jycbDz0g6AjZmipPXSFhMoxUDmGWYIR@LtD/t9bpChH6EnxZnu6PPcDZi9mRc6dlJD0ksc08Y@tSgBE87XZzpBITbRbjgovPoT6pE14h0axIpqsXGuUJtxA9M9xdSA72x0mKR@r5F7cMRz3fXREAgwj1bVHaa0RBO2iUNN2VYyRkgo0WFYO5x2NU6Meymi4ZokkO4LHjZJGSEKx3q3EvKhbGdKw1iiOXrj1RlKu5Und1IyyeXC43T1ccrZBy3Zjif5Qi/L0PG@dEE6oids5bWEfSqeIJb3gFjul7p9NFanq7xXBpsjfN0Jz0hMI@uswGmm6pQNeH2ej09l8yxdXwJnTFc6LccW8oqjcjTlb53Nasbl4HeyeK5cVl/qktNgnssNxY4tW3ogcc42jxFOdPV/1DPw2I/Z0rS5MRJUZdknV4v1G6DOMZIAU1EiWlGMam8h/fhHExK5dH6rPTGcT9DMG8/UlhqgtLZt/tTsLeuJwLMRRI0niplkpmbIrNnOh9apOpOOt0qBcR2VhFTQUauBb2E4q5TkDscDHQrj5Omc7shWGwkvy7UOVW0eDufjJXeL2kWIKPpFMg8avbuIrWUfxvnuaNawvuB0s4SfZK86azVn1BRmk/2VNxMR2kKdOYpzVgW37qnzAyzCitK/h814HRN0BMuNwW20qQhdTxQClbKqsvIqapbprdOJ9AO0W1JbRrrjacaCa@z25ik/YuNGBdOCabhU9qJPbWF6RZ4xaAT8WLE3HNoWPZPbCmVTWKqnm5URLYYkNFD@8x0Z3EbTCofsvOJql12AT5LHSmLjm0YKSOKcsXyH4SIY4xDv7qplCWm3uRruh1oP0zfGpHjUDMgYtFpV9m6SaUwjYTwjsl2mwwdLrLrbu80nAGmRR7qWil/VEQ8aVstIzQNyi19BpyGmh65BW1Ou8se6cRFiwO3qh3JXqTbgns1J4QY6SBzhBrzyM5DOjql4Z7A5/iQA@yR4E8rL4ezlCm2dzuLqLiQ0q/0i5txr5baTycaUcm4Fa0FLOQC@6lWti5kpRMFmytm55SsDrcum9PR1EpvEwuTEoMh8Z2uVDodwl00Mt1KmEAoZASM/ziUgc9dlxaDojT87IhUCTtJeSg5mJ7@kOiNJzEMXD@1J66Yys4M82jBak9xjRs@LNJKpuYhESB5JhVtbJdJ45meeuQ06bEAxXlE71kOA6ZPW3E4LWqFvdvtuLNRT4PoVBe4bZxJVcseB8GBn7qngjtNOGApFxLPdSAxANOtUGlwSmWPcyZwalTgWRT4lOmnkQYCqZl@x@K3TE6N7I2Pqj9migHTptN9rpaBrzXCKNcsZ@DVA5EEnx71LiFBCmEVs7v0k4GOUOZoiZB5Ix6yWN2AcpFyXO5CTGRoBuhJrr3SGc/ywpVCOScY00PCyiIg7ojGNDVrZCnM/I8wW6u7g72bu5jloWpTzACZmvSmMYqWi15GZDN9ZacTJuS9XEg13LDBwVOaDE@yP8jxUJcfugx5nfJk4HAvAOGEy1ui8TC1E2t8MlgY0jnOSUQ5x9j7oYoG9WRuEB@ROQKqCB/cRc05ZHfNQn49Jky6SvUtAQkHmF7YCFtob7Yix7URWd50p3mk2RXazEUmyHsY5NuXs2@8OGK4NHJIC@teDcj2BMCHOwBE4TxcI@JD6QJaNXSnDzsEIGnmVNy4ZFpCtZFsuN9H4MYjR05yTkMq1sYpdBxpVjHdGXuO4RiRt3dEc@6@rSNV1H2dhm@uh@k9XQhntoAJ6OkHtOzIiWnMeUr2XJ@7jrZfW4A8Rsq6QDRW3fqYUk3o6MGyze5WcytQi9S9uTW3wUhluFv7U1aUwsrpLpRuQxc19EnPu@NA6JNkYzBVBiNPhaLrFD70o6PQxj@9NvNeh@GOwLQ72kn3OU@nk2FR0Dzu0slEvZAjTbnmcA/W6UDeWT9V6fSTRHZduvZ4Tz1zmub4jzG9aZb3vHSDiIQiX1SEr3ZE1B07444mLWzaeS@BhLAWzPWe9xos@vcg6pwR7Lr6jhd8uEDAL6qZz6/IOd3ErJBbkd9b5eZWKm4prqDGFVYquVlpXuE3aqRmzguDAYXiON0rxjFhDtuOnMnteGd@k9NBhxrnJhf5OhORtDvpT9k@q8lWKtVPjRvMqgqekovdqZJhJOcVSAOEhegFm0GHi7F8RigW0ot3xjyFwfadUjnk1QV6fJTPA2WZ2xaTQlalzPTSItnS23363qjTabrBJnRrMasFxUP7FUSdRhl0UkKsMNLsEgaHfnhKpgspnvxaR306/UoGJGbDGsDRU9V0NKj0xZhGtCN0RpTQJKen347TfSywn674dURhlehydw1q5xlA2vKZtkgTQKv7x3kFh2tC5qFMSDt/1MS29/M2CBpA0X7bO6tbgo3w@Ln7Jik4lxTaYPcoCdwGY7j5X976Q3ec6YAefdYMvf2ksUwHQ0Cp5YVJcW/TJ7LJPS0wtBZ1uGPWSklnyEkX0rqW2Ykf6cyRovOuKkXwlvlBL8yVWtU@8qqo1Pn27m7fyZsmLFkHeAyKF81NOHU/P3qNQzqizn6E3ssyZ/daWD3WAuvn5hJYrUTEp4tvWJk0hoZcoQAy3a79Lo7xO2v@lLdA2tytr0tXBVowdIPftGBJo6Bx3mwz/AYGO1i1N7PxzZOOle4XBFrLJSMznem6uw8tN/kbtP9xfxauY8G1OyUOtPYhGVnwcV44sNaJ86YpLNfezxm5ODy7AOqK4Kp7mfRWC3rTpCh1hUbu6zlf9BQqotfc1m88deNzmKz349jhkryj0D4FY3icYfmQDCUFuTtBlwqJ4dcYjMgRaHEILFhOCcnaj5Vi9UXDPL/Dy2onSfZopgYKTRMov1/MRLEL7qaFyHbfeBjefmWOkXei9Z52XIuruXIC0d9yYoFXiZy2XbwR5rSOdymaJW0uI4IKm37fBHnKkfcfWA0sUWM/GqnhCjRV7c4UEKPumv005xt@MYA6i6MRmTiHyds9HO0snInLhEQzIqmJcUq@D2aDxtzTfLSbn7ibrqHF0cePwMfp15W4BpLgfkILp6Qm3ZxASo4C3JXAHglu3sWHfnQELbRhpIbN72igM5cpy374ouHXly1rpqlNHXnFkQpLQkiv844UtkfSOUjjzRGNAwCHGvgp6qDb8ZjRPEzvBMR6jvzGnGlhjo7WjP1Ip2bXl3Y4zKQFqfE70v3Z3QBH/sFzAmgbI3mrmcyCqVe/3GZYDT@8qXgB4bQzsjQ6rw9zmjxswUxrfcq6zktmIMrGCMnhd0U5AW3valbfbfP9miAUDUfeMyxGpQNgXsIhugDidVqCDAQdLoO17K@n/jzNiIc/0tOg2EQdApVpMDZ5SeDw6w@wiMjfp@JAvU@CNtg0WErZGG/RTA00sRydyNzh/gQ64VnHsJzRjYzmiGeeaSL5h//3x5988ubXX354eff113//3W/@y5d/9@71b2v7d7/4yctf/MVLf/fu5fXd6z@8vv/2m5e3799@@/bLd2//1@tXL99@/VL@XL/44fUfXz988/ofn37/0/Xpj@ovfvLJ2/ffvrx@@PD1h5efvpSffPL43z9@/farlze/fn3z93/99Yf/@rjYV@Nxjc/2hd58/snLy/9@/Pvy9pcvn3325uUvf/ry6cunn7/8y7@8PP72Vy@f/p9PP78/88LHHv/7zYfHPX752R//7Oc//88///cv98W@fPPt64eXT//kq09fvv7u25evf/n40Ne/eXzrw5fvf/X65//9/R9/8bjVT7iAh1f5xr8@/vjX@9G/N8hP9uP8w5dv3392f/Hlh1@9eVzoHvif/dnjL//4@SePQenvb9//5nHnn77ouf7s88/un/9t/cV91/2t7i@Gv5j@Yj2@uK//4fWXrx9e3795/Y@v73/17a/57r7yx9/hz394@823X/796/t7qOPr795/y5zvyWwvf/TTPeI9fZq835m6n/3zY@Le/c@Xr9@/3p/87l7zl7ffPMbxP757@@H1q3vimLXXf3777WdVf/nXxx1@Z6iPG3/z7Yd3r@8/y1tzP9@DzNDPJ/Y3P7@H@U@/fvvu9eWz50/96Z@@fPbpf3//6ctPf6rf/tunn/74MZ1PT/P8kx//5Hzr@Vd@oSlh1Pe8PN/tMUO/8yC/f7Le@TH@5KsvXr759dffvfvq5e9eH3/T9nq67Bffu@jTHLYzh/3Fz/iYmTe//nDm7ouXT/vjEPz4vIP4cbJexh/6/Pj@5@cf@vz8/ufXH/r8@t7nP8kMrW/evv/V3sr7IH7z8idv9P@XXz4O2m26H3O0Z6l/8TK@eJlfvKy9Ab5vFbrOy@9@e/zwt@cPf1sX3xal3xtpfP4v/6KvZr5a91cj3xv53tRXv38j/Jdfv/7gs3754fXl/dffvvzmy7cf/untN68vXz2O59v3b7798@8/@vfNkLdnvW@/f7RHsPfMtZ/n2Vp/9t37b97@6v3rV5/3e4c/dstPft8Hxv7A@P0fmPsD8/d/YO0PrE9/ss/99y1///T@wG3ffuinY/90/J6fzv3T@Xt@uvZP133jeyd99naf5pe3L3/5kVV8efujH8lJ4CPuicxW/du3v7gP@g8/22dYjF98/gvczHE0L983sD/60T2Wlx9wRC9f3pb6q9d/fliEf/9wRW8@fbmtwhcvucHTb97j@6P//wE93ethne89dlvsh5f79rEVf/n1dx8@3o9f5N/HnP3Jm9@z/fYWfPfN6w/c5Fi3@zn0@z@wPE@Dfp7sz39x7vCvn5wF@b63@qvH5i8/MO0eRy1Zgecn/PGPXz589/7l8fU/vH3/5bcf@anY2X/7PIj939vDP3YR5@x7oznHbf@qp@ZjE/Bff/bzv/nrv/nZf/hdz1hs1fddbsDwyW9/@9t6XbXW1q7Hn1ct5bpKKfffay2PHzy@1r@Pn5dWr/L4//X44f7y8Uv33@@PNX3k8aV@8Ph/u/8sj2@X/WWpj38fn2j3l@X@wePPdt90D@G@n77cv/a4dKv3OOr9wbqHc3/38Zl7BPt6uuz9G3v490/Lfef9s7JHe/9z3@7@pfr0qbZHWO8PVT3s49OPm7X7F@8HfEzCpc/vh7s/do@k7l/fY6n3T@9P339ee6z31R8fvgexB7u/ukeoSxeNr9X9z/0Ye3j3c@zrVo1zr8c9mnuamMh72u5B7Gmpe8xl3/cegJbnXoF79PcM7VnYD3@P/h5WqxrT/dH7wvdv3Q94//ceR9tXbvuh7xlrmu99o3rtp93TfD/VPaRrP9C@b9vT5UnbF2z38O6tcO8dP0G5F1yzpH807fuye/33vOwRPH7hcZ37ae@fFhZzf@S@wd4b95xotu9fYrruj@15bXsOtX5avHvi94j3SuohNfh7aPfCaFmvtr/eQ77v/rjLnoOqrazpvcezD4j24h7wvvv9qHXPw57Pve21oPto7dtqf@yn3rfZ99zHZ@9NrtuaTpQOQtlz1bRx6z4k9z8Mu@4B76e@P69V2bu1sQG0bfZj7Y/pkNS9E66LX9Rv36tU9Y3Ln3h8617U@xd1APbc3iPZ9oJf3YtWNeX3fS6MR2vet2zePTkcjX3hvbltYTjl@4S1fTB0x313Lrl32R67TuOlp9ex3nuEXaol0nG6N8veMxq85l@buDQ/kjdS8wRo@e6Nqw/7VG5TtRe7bLO37R2Xrazcfop9JG7joYNU91neG0KrVrct2JtcJ@biYYumSPt3H0Ofmn1G7t2oedZM7L2K8ZVl3ntVZ1uXLUxR0a/tw@gNWdve3Toc@0l0V5k2Pdq2YzrDMg6yV3ufsMMvDr62yd5znNsqi6SJ0ergM3yR/eH7sfap2evRZBMv2XwNdz9E8XLpcF/Nbuy2dZfsiUyXPJluWreBaDp9l@6@V1JGld1ZsbGy740xc9b28xU9433EddivqrO@/4tVxw1oLuWPZJPuMyMveLFF2zbje4fs9WnHrWwbLMOzn@S@L@5qH78qN3p52xZt/70h6/5TH9pGQFO6L7GvVbaV3ZPR9q7YM68V96LrIO5z1GzOK1e4yhXbe2F4qwxplVktOuzZyg0/dmm@ZdDa/s626Tqle3N61Xye5Oo0QRdLvg/ZHm1WufgzXlLute2xjiCH6cIW7Ttg1OyxdZc9nZcsCnugsUOKDYi21fZHWs16MQyQzj6wVbuA09D8XKUwI/iovQZyCWCr7dRLjVEGAF3yB/rFCm7DvOxraxMKM1wxI9rG2loyKhWPo12xHwFTtr/Yn9GCbJcC8Lkq/rHFzAgwCHVsxyFz3wTptocEe@wDtbewYWY1@KxnyvayyvgXDnfVqd@PILe4v@Spiz9UWWud3FLt4/A72hf7a49P9ofLbFOzzxtbXyDWp/GSMxLck73FbzS8wLa12iL2WO3SAax2G3U7E2ELVqTpsm3jXc6pjnuROeQDLKIOkY/WPuJVCyOMdRmKFK7csLF2Z5VD5H/2wm6XiFdlnTQa2Ttdavs9kHO186ksjVwqCOUql0@t71LOHbWzuGaTK2RH4CP0120Ttu1RSFA5xZqbY@Ux8ttBVaHcilER/rvOHrYpEMSq7BaZXfw7EU1RVLJvIPQlsCQ8ImsiT9SO@9DcsHt1vaZttmH6vtSlTS@bkcCACIZYRKbpI6O9V2hP42Wc4EXZwFaf3Cax2ExdYAY9uZ7y9vg6qFUI5MKWtAvQhHUthlxXjmKrNqOA4ItDV@IFdA8iMBki0FOp9vD68R7Y5aO9p9rnL3Yas6PYU9tj21cNjDPSGDtHuypgBZ8IuCkkKNytBncAUDOrWNwN@ff@uQpQEKMq8Ki4WUej5jjEbtTEjmxyMLBMXGEt2DkYZQHaFqegmStXLKqeg/CAAOHChWspC45Fx9BIQxtb21VgrOB1dSuCxG1H6uU9UwMD5HG8eXTAOSh2H8SmBHE6ng10XBUUyr3aNzQOiE5v1WQWI@u2LUBrNnWY9wJmUOysncjW46pXrg6MwhpuxAOWODa/2LeWCzMBHLFVgwIQ7tiWVjEyzrcVUAaEgBkQlq8mnNVpkWMpwA7wPCbF3ksMRZNrqJwLYtrqh5JfqY4Y9wxrVWXBK8c/4TNo0xsIW1IAhYL8skWO6Z7MWsMLyidoCksWUd5K88bsCYg5MvIzX17HS3bVdAAPEk9R9Kwg5CL4JzOlAASQLyeiiKZcdg@X7Jpon0p8GTOF@8tmuSr7as/nvthGU4o3jLcvDulF2OxbXdVkCOdpzw8@peFigLo@43sDKya65KmKdxJwohI3ynpdlUcDf5mHulgjcKlOKycRByQ4AkJoxzMxvwQaHAdgVRF5JWcKfGqCIsUzK7JFHrMQxW@QtIdt5gNI54NpWogwzpvhwotUn3OhqezsCw9VxF9d9kUKM/fxk4tIcMHKNT2LjRsLDQqxpfL2rtVRpQ/R9imyYiKpGmsHAKuxkNVQHGz45G2E5qsxnp6E2BhkXoi32hUDn@U21BEaaI6YQOn1Ys63vY1Fx4XhO735NKli67TAQLjK@ZVF0jnQ3fcYTRNdjijl1DPDgojERK0AF@vlaWhEFg3r3aB6S2UMIjKg5rIZ7AGJN0SWVMUFV4B0JQivDfNZYw@qmM8LMGwGquBr8bbFJ8XrVo2r64mCT/R2GZ9UMSJ4rsvOne9wNku2m7ZAq1Do5YlfF99VOf/lgmAEpfH8mCzZdrklA7/rDF/Tm8EUaBPMXnliPMSqlAKbWqsDK7z3Ve19gIVyKPAd2VcgXrsUIFBl0lo5uFGxkMleEU98Hqtwhd901Cq7pp1ZDKtgkjZjSFjk6ATu5Z7JDaKbgPBliFvE9dkh6prlSnhy2UjFCyRoh0lVjHaJgtRpVSJBRIqofk1bycLoAQEBQqYOJ0W2NewqA7uS3LjsKUQf4zTrddYXtpBzKzIIKkxPCLY35w9OLsQjtUHdb8pFF9eaitS6IDnwnjpvgMkTgtUQ9jqf3pMtZ@cywFNYg6cMya3zCcQH4BDYw@wUvDjMXtGlmmPAauKa6MAkgPILsLuaIVj3iyFd3jmaTKwFLk4WkTyVpu9pBS5ngZzYuAAfij9ZxKse2KxBwBfB87Co2sTNHoqoz9RFwrorrK9Zm/xiuY5598yXxLPxPpepf6VL@E6gqW3zpUDiCvjG1BSzr2SmBIabJ0fpkotbabT8CJBZYGlJDFZSINiMSzGhVkyZJ0NBwbOr@N6OP5JFxLRW@Mwisp/rwTXYY/LkImx9A1laghPdwIFwmEnQlBNv9onmkYugAkYfL5/bVtvGaucCHUOoQvqjOYQnT8SMF@wNZ6X5xFx8kZg5OaY4YqI/EJJCmqYHwLjbNjW5qtjA7e9keuRxyc@yxxR86eiRUdC/Pt7wbAU@R@khWAJzsfz/pGbKZYSs@LvhOACTongupzJgJ0Cj4RYrrHrGJxq8EILvcAlQrscoNfsKBinmRFFAISMq0@LouHk2ihlXnDE0j8FnYbMqeZstpBhNkIDNBwvqoATXSdRZTGba4jkHW01SgV65OEegKoJzRu4iuhQ9GAsgqJx0CSkeM@tKYhRiErMWl9JqySVgSoQNS1IXyV8X4gwSr6WY@QHoEc3e81lEpxJdN2kTGrmlqziGat5ol3OexIYX8cjFetllmZbRaog@CHfHI1zgXgZeMAd4nFZLXKFNRDVZLX90EHsjLXisVTPFThh0gJlpoQJLdXlsNqFXjkIh008mP9ltQJ2A3wUtv8GJgqGgOyd6lN32shYiaOGBC6lByHqQpxPEB1XoSB2msdpn1fBdpZjwlvGHLS/JDGlvSgTSLMPQF5tHBNc7vK8nk3iRgmPh4AytOSGFQSbsMprFRAj1nwjlcPdQlGZNAWbHnl9OI@qME900cTPC9gmcOOGBNg225LCmMkbICVCc4IYE3wQNYbHIKJbi3VBJR@XKdsxWK3DkHc63C/lJ1CawnrYzRhHN9oTLNfL2Jdi@nuAa00/0eFkjAXnbymVEBrWuPMN10iLV4gEn3YgEFCkF/m24Xrzf5KM3qJHfq4ZXhPAmPKrBEBGRc7t2ARc0eQHP1RLIh7rkKk64XiJrL@gInKg8GfvQcNgrkqhY@Shjj0wFEat29IV@CREOIemVrK7G2LBUhVinWAdSyV1Gq8FBrLYkga0JySG5RQ/I6x@scp37kVMzedLIuR6jBQMl4vSKgGdnt6sjTcJ0qRV2@HsRKNVQ@hDdO6SV@WIpycY6xIPvKwc/F3yKVmzrdwBTxcwa4iZJupDKOIHm8JxpK84Fi20ototP4BeFy4VsSjAICCcyrYEY8yTRk9gzmbN1/OuspabNCrkCdpLgxaKu5GXQL5XEcXhDb81toxSJQA9ekQ01y5Og/Ys5@OpDCES1S7MdaPi7CyAq1ktUCfYJyR/wo1iiUdD62ZAXoGV7pqq15T2lzQvkbbQDO3i2ckhXgGIpIRvRqAFfm/MZ2nTKFglRXWcvI9IyEesMaFG29sIntuJnqCZajerb4dCkbJQrlR9ryYIlI1dsTY0uPBuWkySEJzgTNclG1PYuLHlxUunynhfnfJnnSZht5lDpkULulQjI2Wg9S7Emp0ReJxUT5wAU7VjbuEraNQ4JYrTWDH8tS7LCp9pOW2NxFGtWWwF5Ob9OjBVnJpLZQ/BCtqWcDLyzacXeHKtQsDH6r4QaRPaXD2fMtOPAShLIpDrA6XKKx3@9EkSXY/IbeWyTqJjpwg@zFwvyLvjwi6AFb6XBmWlpxA9we4VhNMO2BmjmzF7VrEFLkthBIZGmntS4qCUKJHPCxUmqFbBDs@CjleuIcRp5k3pCDfIPCJIBRKTAyMARiDn/WqI5veBuPWemkSFkQCCkYIyZAXXiDa9wENVCOhg1pLXObJlorShDsVj1cq7TCkC0OobvdvsOjZvp1OAG0UbVNA0SpIMimiUkzax2cJZOHWdF34ce2wkX@QzwvZBYQTpxJRVldZ5tI4aK0EynqmbjFZwIvJQCSQ6edsjhLC2aBlZrSRA2Kxa@wiRrNRPZHr7@OoQBLCVIAf6XxJy9sF1BSV5SOwgFRUNvICtyMiFHGINddzIEzu1yxkTpoVI9/8hhFVZciD1sBGwtWzXLUC1jv0L4BJ9bo5KkdihqHtHWu0ZZJEm7znmNSgRfb1YLbpkTpNNqfQdT0Mg1l@htGs/ueL/a55Zjf@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@Q8fyUdERUYnLVcWck@DIvPFDYj3lZPehWEQYYRG2x9WMKT1qJlQjVSAgEcDTigsmBWe6SU@mSiCC/Y0o24Izobck5PYSj7mRi9IJESGX5FdirBB2442QZ0KOakoolrsKMyCuR7WoonWLhmgFmO2FVMfCK12iKyJvIoR1JqzOLErJ0DwTY7BOE@dTGwEXIvISwR8PrnjidU9HCKS4qzXcULh2pyG4TWTPS5GAKVLLkXS@Kuk6v0JDgYEt9ZVdWkW1QoUIdCVtBfQKHviadtpg05m5k22GLV4VXLQlqyMRf1XZdcUomXphijHANbStIWKiWzqDllbpVklPVTKNYt3SKdQW5ZnH1zPlyQBPx3pVpMFvXCPpAHcAykbJi8SKhuGL6LxCnoGFPLblXCoEabKGu3a3S07y2K8WXI1IrnqWbPkHc2p7Bi3IjzTJHGYCLDEpeAWbCHTx0ElrCY/b4smgCOEnwW6jXMN5RaU6nUYuBF5ijMqY630L8QymgSmiEi3Nql6g3Luni2Aj9lUaLiVjSoBrBOfaNfgJmDG3FNcYuCvp69QYLiua4ERqoG7KgINSrMku2HVsQPyw459pkPKk9AVqOyG6G0GaiZZfgUkbKlnQLBZl1gUoTCdOKmLjBlIUyHRdFOLtXMNAFUDFGkA@iZMU8tRWGNuBU8WFwyCfoxA@BgjvQ1IbI9u9xpgU3FiZNDA6aqXra00OMu71BaBvftgKz43FMILGRbgPNmKbhXxl/Y9uygywlJ/aZ9C3Ad74H0XFAKE5MK8xomUdbNysrnnIwtcTVNxEb2ZkAqWwP1C2XDhqsO9IUEmsnDVsLW1HClkeEVZI9FHIXTSk43H3G1aVpSZOj7UTKiM72s@do2D@1Steq/BcgxGgIGEocAM2IvFDrVwyiR/gndWxcMhjh6FsOEyz0HEqmjoVF@H9rgOqnsGo2Q7WWrJXV/LZVtTqi1clLkrs/Q07Qki6Wn2HCgeH/I75CXs2M3ARkiR@iAerGGIKKZ4a7eiM16EJeGaBFdl6MGBD66V/RfOgbVumlk/onV4E9rdOguV632LE/lyFInhv@IaBZR15V5s/Q5xSHs3hr/WZ3hsywFyy2J5uVTVC0JoTKkVFf1UcTZYkJl5YBSLm/kaUDlsE7VZKe2arP62ME0Oqsaxp1iStk2pOuuSyvUXTtGLLGBl2ptAat@KqvxUqRh1Z8RI54eVyvV7WkEQYVruyKGulw5YRIihZgtm@Fyhr4CyRtSqNIsC7@suSkJ3Bx@oSitQVa4ONcUUB/k4u@zggjG1FzB@m6StIi@Re5eqQOO9ryK8qFi@nLJu@u2Tm2Ypo6siszvDkjRNW2ZksZqtUW9nmKly6VmtiLN@WFX5Vb7zgNEQ1NGlpXiG1d1tHLS71aK2U94OtV7wzuuOrUoNbNnjEr5eirSyEo6Q@FqLvNMBQtE1XsLWXCdakirDgkmPc@c@ssqARdfY/R4dnducQBFOthRjOX4NeeNrheoaqrRBSXaRk3FcjeDqtQau7VAbeGq7UgsYasuOWokOVLQI9xMcKY6WexqMh4xRKTjz/bI@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@tZcosT5zdbfU7XWtniylQ6eTias@YwCVbXe2VbXqmjSaGtsRBjQE2HlFBZMhkf8@aRgja3CKnWkVBUEi1EpL7IzmUkgANup@N47bD9EHlRa4ZutJ63uFrIpeoFUhlEd6Xs/0k@386csKlccOrMeIGCczB7qpoiC7H/LS7ibQC/cuoO00YotLhJM2XD2nPa6fpevd3zwrkelDVK9wbEFdYbBK3Er5XUOlqDT1uOQ6Eh5Im@IqxFomwrqyWsIIVtMYs8KWoiel20HDeHjWKwMNv44mdm@6llV7RRkPLFuegW4RhQ24oVbR5Lz2gSF7PMKiL0c9GI5YcRr4EdlF4s1hWaNL1gtq1mclTKH6mhpAArKL6dvnfllCNQ706Lrev0LCo4OXlTy1U899USZDfpqMba1ZbEHQAvN16qz2Uc55hXAj9zevIXrpQ1PUK9yHVQUjVzWY3EcL2qnkccX5@aXlh8SlWl@2SgySxp2nH6iWxIITlbpK4lJR3Pcj/XOKJoMKfTggRS2UC2paTghsKvcsXrU2cB6YS60w1R0kwLuFyutM0QWKVBASxdS@tJt9xwzE7xE00TT7U/afxy2jXA/lkmbKW8a/KpR9bJKMZIJRWcNJkj4rM6OiaIeq9K1VlSgu3UnUeSjYdvkXQEbLQUJ18lYTGNVgxgLsMM@Vik/WmvVxUi1CP8tDjbHX2KsxGtJuNKz056SGKZa8LQpwYleNrm4kwnINwuwgUXlUd/UiW6RqRak0hRLTbOFWolfqC5v5Aa6JUrLRap77uofTji@eqaCAhEuGeLyk4zGsJJu6TipgxXcgbIaFEhmHssdrVODLvpoiGa5BAuC75sEjLCKx3q3EvKhbGVKxViiMvXL6nKVNypOruSlk8uFyqnq49XyDjuauF8Lkf49TJkbB9NoI7YOWtpHUGviie45R1QmuuVTh@ty9NVnkuDrXFu7qQnBObRVTZAc1MVqibcXq@m55I5toovoTOGC/0ux5aySiXydKXvXc3qxmWgd7J4blxWn@pSk@AulxsLnNo29MClHG2eopzm6n@o52KxnzMlaXLipKhLsk6vF2q3QRylpIAmosQ0o2hU3sP7cA4apfJofa70xnE/QzBvPVJYaoLS2bf6U7C3ricCzEUSVJ4qZZKZayKzWzofWqTqTjrVKgXEdlYRU0FGrgW9hOKuU5BbHAxUK4@TpnO7IVhsJL8u1DlVtHg7n4wrvV/SLEBG0ymQdtTs1UVqKf82znNHtYT3BaWdJfokedNZqz6hojSfrKm4aY7SFOi0U5pxWXzrnjItzCqsKPl/1IDNNUFPuNwU2JUmDanjgVKwUlZdRk5V3WV663QCrRDdltSmsV55qpHwOruNSdq/2Ihx4ZRgGj6lndhTW5hqgVcMOhEvRsw9h4pl/8SWUtkkpqrpRkVkiwEpNbRPS3cWt8Gk8iE7n6jaZRfgs9SRsujYhpIyoihXLP9BiFhKOfSrm0pZYupNfjW3A62H6btK5DjUDIhYdNpVtq5RKUwjIbxjst0mQ4uL7KrbOxVngGmRh7pWyh8VETfaVssINYNyS58Bp6GmS25Bm9Pqskc6cdHiwK1qS7IX6bbgXs0JIUo6yByhRjuy85COTmm4J/A5PuQAayT4zcrL4ixliu3dziIqLqT0V/rFtbhXS@2bE42oZNyK1gIWcoH1VCtbF3KlEwWbK2bnlKwWty5rzdHUld4mFiYlBkPi21ypdDqEu2ikuZUwgVDICBj/cigDn7sqLQZFafjZEqkSdpLyUHIwNf0h0Rs3Yhi4fmpPXDGVnRnm0YLVmuIaN3y4SCuZmodEgORpVLSxXRqNZ2rqkdOkxwIU5xG9ZzkMmD5txeK0qBX2brfjzkY1DaJTXeC2cSZVLXssBAd@6poK7jThgKW8kHheBxIDMN0KlQanVPY4ZwKnRgWeRYFPmX4aaSCQaul3LH7L5FTJ3vio@qOlGDBtOt3n6jLwtUYY5ZrlDLx6IJLg06PeJSRIIaxidpd@MtARyhwtETJvxEMWqxtQXqQcL3chJjI0A/Qk177SGc/ywiuFck4wpoeElUVA3BKNaWrWyFKY@S9htq7qDvZu7mKWh6pNMQNkatKbxihaLvoyImvpK9ucMCHv5UKq4oYNDp7SZLiR/UGOh7r80GXI65QnA4d7AQgnXN4SjYepnVjjk8HCkLZyTiLKOcZeD1VUqCdzg/iIzBFQRfjgLmrOIbtrFvLr0mDSVapvCUg4wPTCRthCe7Mrclwbkcub7jSPNLtCm7nIBHkPg3z75ewbL44oLo0s0sK6VwOyPQHw4g4AUTgX14j4ULqAVg3d6cMOAUiaORU3LpmWUK0kG@73EbjxyJGTnNOQirVyCh1LmlU0d8ZupThG5O0d0Zy7b2tJFXW9TsM318PUmi6ELVvABHTzA1p25MQ05jwle67PvY62X1uAPEbKukA0Vt36mFJN6OjBss3qVnNXoBape3NrboORynC39qesKIWVzV0o3YYuauiTnnfHgdAnycZgqgxGngpFr1P4UI@OQhv/9NrMex2KOwLT7mgn3Vs7nU6KRUHtuEsnE/VCjjTlasU9WJsDeWf9VKVTTxLZdena4zX1zGma4z9K86a5vOelG0QkFPmiIny1I6Lu2Bl3NGlh0857CSSEtWCu1rzX4KJ/D6LOFsGuq@94wYcLBPyimvb8ipzTTcwKuSvye6vc3ErFLcUV1LjCSiU3V5pX@I0aqZnzwmBAoThO94pyTJjDtiNncjvelt/kdNChxrnJi3ydiUjandSnbJ/VZFcq1U@NG8yqCp6Si92pkmIk5xVIA4QL0Qs2gw4X5fIZoVhIL94p7RQG23dK5ZBXF@jxUT4XlGVuW0wKWZUyzUuLZEtv96l7ozan6Qqb0K3FrBYUD@1XEFUaZdBJCbFCSbNLGBz64SmZLqR48msV9WnzKxmQmBVrAEtNVdPRoNIXoxnRltAZUUKTnG5@O071scB@uuLXEYVVope7a1A7zwDSls@0RZoAWt1fzis4XBPSDmVC2vmjJra1nrdB0ACK9tveWdUSbITHz903ScG5pNAGu0ZJ4DYYxc3/8tYfuuM0B/Tos1ro7SeNZToYAkotL0yKe5s@kU3uaYGhtajDHbOulHSGnHQhrWuZnfiRzhwpOu@qUgRvmR/0QrtSq1pLXhWVOt9a3e07edOEJdcBHoXiRXMTTt23j17jkI6orR6h92WZs3stXDXWAuvn5hJYrUTEp4tvWJk0hoZcoQAy3a79Lo7yO2v@lLdA2lytr0tXBVowVIPftGBJo6By3mxT/AYGO1i1N7PxzZOWK90vCLQul4y0dKar7j50uclfof2P@7NwHQuu3SmxoLUPyciCl/PCges6cV4zheXa@9YiF4dnF0C9IriqXia91YLeNClKvUIj1@s5X/QUKqLX3NavPHXjc5is9@PY4ZK8o9A@BWN4nGL5kAwlBbk7QZcKieLXGJTIEWhxCCy4nBKStS9XitUvGub5HV5WO0myRzM1UGiaQPn9YiaKXXDXLES2@8bD8PYrc4y8E63WtOO6uJorJxD9XU4s8CqR07aLN8Kc1vEuRbOkzWVEUGHN75sgT1ny/gOrgSVqrEcjVVyBpqrdlgJi1F2tnuZ8xS8GUGdxNCIN59B4u4ejnQtn4jIh0YxIamKcku@D2aAxdzMf7eYn7qZraHH08SXwsfl1Ja6BJLhv0MIpqUk3J5CSowB3JbBHgpt38aEfHUELbRipYfM7GujMZcqyHr6o@PVllzXT1KaWvOJIhSUhpK/zjhS2R9I5SOPNEZUDAIsa@CnqoNtxadE8NO8ExHqO/EpraWGOjtaMfUmnZteXVjjMpAWp8TvS/VbdAEf@wXMCaCsleauWzIKpV7/cplgNX7ypeAFhszOyNDqvD3OaPGxBS2t9yrrOS2YgykoJyeF3RTkBbe9qVt9t8/2aIBQNR95TLEalA2BewiG6AOK1WYIMBC0ug7Xsr6b@PM2Iiz9S06DYRB0ClWYw1nhJYPHrD7CIyN@b4kC9T4I22DRYStkYb9FMDTSxHJ3I3OH@BDrhWUuxnNGNjFqJZ25pIvmH//d/3/zy3Ze/@ua3P/5vX7579/jv45/9ouL/Bw)

Comment: I don't know Keg, but surely this can be shortened!

Comment: Someone has to do this for every challenge

Comment: @MitchellSpector As it turns out, it can only have ~100 bytes knocked off.

Comment: Surely you can do something like push a large number, convert to base 4 and index into ACTG?

Comment: @JoKing Keg doesn't have base conversions. And indexing applies to the whole stack, so no. I can't.

Comment: Well, Keg surely has div and mod right? Convert it to base 4 manually and then you can index the stack into ACTG?

Comment: As this solution does not appear to be a serious contender (no attempt made at golfing, and surely there's a way to shorten it), I'm deleting it, but feel free to edit it to fix the issue and then flag for moderator attention so it can be undeleted. Thanks!